# Sing Happy Birthday to your favourite programming language

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Your favourite programming language has just had a birthday. Be nice and sing it the **Happy Birthday** song.

Of course you should accomplish this by writing a program in that language.
The program takes no input, and writes the following text to the standard output or an arbitrary file:

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear [your favourite programming language]
Happy Birthday to You
```

You should substitute the bracketed part (and omit the brackets).

This is a code golf — shortest code wins.

### UPDATE

I'm glad that the question aroused great interest. Let me add some extra info about scoring. As stated originally, this question is a code golf, so the shortest code is going to win. The winner will be picked at the end of this week (19th October).

However, I'm also rewarding other witty submissions with up-votes (and I encourage everybody to do so as well). Therefore although this is a code-golf contest, not-so-short answers are also welcome.

### Results

Congratulations to [Optimizer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31414/optimizer), the winner of this contest with his 42 byte long, CJam [submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39754/40695).

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 39752; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we count the name of the programming language as one byte because it would only seem fair to people coding in a long-winded language such as JavaScript vs. someone doing it in C. We are really looking for most creative logic right?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry, but taking length differences into account is intended. Since you don't have to be the shortest to gain popularity points, it shouldn't matter too much. There is also a tendency that programs written in a programming language that has a longer name, need less characters to implement the same functionality.

Comment: I am no cross-programming guru but if 2 languages happen to achieve the goal in the same amount of logic bytes then it's kind of like getting penalized for getting your coffee from a "coffee shop" compared to a "café". Disclaimer: I am not a coffee connoisseur.

Comment: Why all the upvotes for this despite all the downvotes for the [Bonbon song](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2259/20260)? This is just as boring a challenge.

Comment: @DavidFrank "Sorry, but taking length differences into account is intended. Since you don't have to be the shortest to gain popularity points, it shouldn't matter too much." Um, it's code golf, not a popularity contest. Votes are irrelevant and the shortest program wins. So you *are* being penalized for, e.g., writing in Microsoft Visual C++ rather than vanilla C (though, in that case, it's probably deserved).

Comment: I should probably mention that the [song is copyrighted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Birthday_to_You#Copyright_status) and distributing these programs may cause a DMCA

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm sorry that the rules are not to your liking. I think this is more or less widespread practise to include the programming language name in the solution. Votes are not irrelevant (you gain xp by votes), though you might not win the contest. However, you have a free choice in your favourite programming language. In this contest not only solutions but also programming languages compete.

Comment: @xnor Not sure, but people seem to [like it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35257/draw-the-sawtooth-alphabet) any time you make them put their language name in the output.

Comment: With the sheer number of answers, this seems to be more of a pop-con than code golf... How are you going to be able to find the shortest answer?

Comment: @xnor Because the Bonbon song never made it to the HNQ.

Comment: [guys! Happy Birthday song is now in public domain!!](http://t.co/4bqFQlMMky)

Comment: At least one of the answers prints a *leading* newline. Is that allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We're no strangers to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i)

Comment: Hmm.. if anyone posts more than one answer to this question, they must be lying. It says to use your *favorite* programming language.

Comment: "Tasks that depend on a language's name are a form of [disadvantaging some languages by arbitrary criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058)." -- quote Martin Ender from [this closed challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150870).

Comment: Gotta make a language called `to You` someday ehh?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### CJam, <s>46</s> [42](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%22Happy%20Birthday%20to%20You%0A%22%5F%5F%5FF%3C%22Dear%20CJam%0A%22%40) bytes

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"___F<"Dear CJam
"@
```

**How it works:**

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"___                          "Push "Happy Birthday to You\n" string to stack 4 times";
    F<                        "From the last string, take only first 15 characters. F is a";
      "Dear CJam              "preinitialized variable whose value is 15";
"                             "Push "Dear CJam\n" to stack";
 @                            "Take the third string from end and put it to end";
```

This leaves the stack as following at the end of the code:

```
["Happy Birthday to You
" "Happy Birthday to You
" "Happy Birthday " "Dear CJam
" "Happy Birthday to You
"]
```

which are printed automatically to output as

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear CJam
Happy Birthday to You
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) (Copy the code and run it)

Comment: does the "first 15 characters" thing come from the F? is that how it knows the number 15?

Comment: Yeah, a-f are 10-15.

Answer (score 121):

## LOLCODE: 109 (105 with "correct" spelling)

LOLCODE is not a great language for golfing, especially since you lose all the beauty and expressiveness when shortening the code.

```
HAI
H R "HAPPY BIRTHDAY "
T R SMOOSH H "TO YOU"
VISIBLE T
VISIBLE T
VISIBLE SMOOSH H "DEAR LOLCODE"
VISIBLE T
```

[Test it using loljs](http://asgaard.co.uk/misc/loljs/)

This is my preferred rendition, weighing in at 187 characters (spaces added for clarity):

```
HAI
H R "HAPPY BERFDAY "
IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR N TIL BOTH SAEM N AN 4
  VISIBLE H!
  BOTH SAEM N AN 2, O RLY?
    YA RLY
      VISIBLE "DEER LOLCODE"
    NO WAI
      VISIBLE "2U"
    OIC
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
KTHXBAI
```

Comment: I just knew there'd be a LOLCODE answer to this. BTW, kan u wryt n lwrcase insyd t kwotez? KTHXBYE.

Comment: I tried writing a LOLCODE answer to another challenge a while back, but it's too verbose for code golfing, and it lacks decent data structures and the ability to create complex functions, so that rather limited my efforts!

Comment: This answer has given me an urge to download LOCODE and actually learn it properly.

Comment: This is great!!

Answer (score 92):

## Mathematica- barcode birthday wishes--way too many bytes

This prints the verses and reads them aloud.

[image: happy birthday]

> Happy Birthday to You
> Happy Birthday to You
> Happy Birthday Dear Mathematica
> Happy Birthday to You

`StringReplace` replaces each comma with a NewLine. Barcodes cannot contain control characters.

Comment: I can't see a barcode button on my keyboard! How can I test this?

Comment: I love that there's a `10` in the barcode (bottom right corner), seeing that `BarcodeRecognize` was introduced in Mathematica 10. ^^

Comment: Yes! I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I actually scanned this with a QR code reader. It has extra spaces after every comma, couldn’t you save bytes if you— oh, wait. Never mind.

Comment: @Timwi, The code replaces the comma with a new line code".

Answer (score 60):

## TI-Basic, 53 bytes

Well, since everyone is putting their favorite programming language up, I might as well add one of my old favorites. I spent a lot of time over the years (before I graduated to actual programming languages) typing commands into a window half the size of a smart phone.

```
"HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO YOU
Disp Ans,Ans,sub(Ans,1,15)+"DEAR TI-BASIC
Ans
```

My calculator doesn't support lowercase letters, and the only variables that can be strings are Str1, Str2 etc.

Comment: Which flavor of TI-Basic? I got really familiar with it on the TI-84.

Comment: Always nice to see TI-Basic.  This appears to be standard 8x TI-Basic, where any expression is automatically stored to Ans, which can be used a weird and hard-to-follow optimization strategy.  I also got started programming with this awesome language.

Comment: Note to editors: can you post any changes (in this case loss of 8 chars) in the comments rather than just editing it? That would make me feel like this is still my answer.

Comment: +1!! that's how i learned to program too. I built Tron for the TI-83 :D it was quite slow though, thus not fun.

Comment: Haha that's awesome.  I made a Blackjack game for the TI-83.  In the process I learned all the rules of Blackjack quite intimately.

Comment: This brings back fond memories of programming on my TI-83. I'm sad I lost it during my undergraduate... would be fun to go look at the stuff I had written 15 years ago now (damn that's a long time ago).

Comment: There are lowercase letters on your calculator, but typing them in is nontrivial and they take 2 bytes each.

Comment: TI-BASIC commands are one-/two-byte *tokens*, so this would be 63 bytes. Also, as Thomas Kwa said, you technically do have lowercase letters, but you can't access them under normal conditions (you can write an assembly program and convert it to machine code to be run with `AsmPrgm` that messes with the system flags and allows you to type lowercase letters)

Comment: Once I tried to write a Pong program in my TI-84 Plus, but gave up due to the sheer scale of the program and small display size.

Answer (score 46):

## Sed, <s>60</s> 55 bytes

(1 character added because there is no way to make `sed` to work without input.)

```
s/^/Happy Birthday To You/
h
G
G
G
s/To You/Dear sed/3
```

Certainly not a winner, posted to demonstrate `sed`'s rare `s///` feature of replacing just the *n*<sup>th</sup> occurrence.

```
bash-4.3$ sed 's/^/Happy Birthday To You/;h;G;G;G;s/To You/Dear sed/3' <<< ''
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear sed
Happy Birthday To You
```

### Sed (shorter but not interesting): 52 characters

```
s/^/Happy Birthday To You/
h
G
p
s/To You/Dear sed/
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ sed 's/^/Happy Birthday To You/;h;G;p;s/To You/Dear sed/' <<< ''
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear sed
Happy Birthday To You
```

Comment: `sed` answers are always winners IMO :)

Comment: The shorter answer appears to be 51 bytes, rather than the 52 you have listed

Comment: @TaylorScott, the explanation at the top applied there too: “(1 character added because there is no way to make `sed` to work without input.)”.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 30):

## C, 73 bytes

```
main(c){for(;c-5;)printf("Happy Birthday %s\n",++c-4?"To You":"Dear C");}
```

Comment: Insignificant bug: should be `i++-3`. (Currently the “Dear c” appears in the 2nd line.) (While using a single variable, I would name it “c”.)

Comment: constant fixed, variable changed.
Any idea to shorten the code?

Comment: Sorry, no idea to shorten it. C is not my strength. (I found the bug because even your current score is so unbelievable to me that I had to try it out. ;) )

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Dear C" (uppercase)?

Comment: I miss also the interpunction characters there...

Comment: Maybe https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6XUMTjJRcUhOLFJxjDJRA/Nr///8lp@Ukphf/13VJ1yjWLCgtKdZQ8kgsKKi0dcosKslISaxUUCpWCslXiMwvVdK0BgA

Answer (score 29):

### Python, <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 59

```py
H="\nHappy Birthday to You"
print(H*3)[:60]+"Dear Python"+H
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte - `H="\nHappy Birthday to You"` and `print(H*3)[:59]+" Dear Python"+H`

Comment: @StretchManiac: Nice, thanks! (I guess if my trailing newline was ok, the preceding one is ok as well...)

Comment: Is this python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: @George: Python 2.7, as it has no brackets around the `print` argument.

Comment: Does output from an interactive interpreter count? `h="\nHappy Birthday to You";(h*3)[:60]+"Dear Python"+h`

Comment: You can save one more by removing the space before `Dear` and changing `59` to `60`.

Comment: @threed: Thanks, that's great! But no, I don't think the interactive interpreter counts.

Answer (score 26):

## sh, 52

```
H()(echo Happy Birthday ${@-to You});H;H;H Dear sh;H
```

Comment: With default value parameter expansion just 53 characters: `H()(echo Happy Birthday ${@:-to You});H;H;H Dear sh;H`.

Comment: Ooh very good @manatwork!

Comment: You can omit the colon in the parameter expansion - that works if the parameter was never set, while `:-` also covers cases when it is set but empty

Comment: @professorfish Nice - thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma A good place to look if you need to save characters is http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe - there's a list of all parameter expansion syntax

Answer (score 22):

## [ArnoldC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language#ArnoldC), 228 bytes

Lets make [Arnold Schwarzenegger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Schwarzenegger) singing...

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
TALK TO THE HAND "Happy Birthday to You"
TALK TO THE HAND "Happy Birthday to You"
TALK TO THE HAND "Happy Birthday Dear ArnoldC"
TALK TO THE HAND "Happy Birthday to You"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

output:

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear ArnoldC
Happy Birthday to you
```

Comment: [`Invalid input '\', expected '"' (line 2, pos 40)`](http://www.youtube.com/v/iy_BBBGBpqA?autoplay=1)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage lol, fixed.

Comment: Perhaps you can add an Ahnold lisp! `Hahpy Birfday` reduces character count by 4.

Answer (score 22):

### [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_%28programming_language%29), 3429 bytes

> no one is going to be demented enough to enter a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge with SPL, so...

My own words, a while ago. And yet, someone was demented enough to do it. Yes, yes, I know. Too much bytes. But SPL deserves to be included here, I think. And *believe* me, I've done a gargantuan effort to "golf" this program, which is why it's a bit repetitive and uses mostly the same words (I could always have followed [DLosc's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/tips-for-golfing-in-the-shakespeare-programming-language/48933#comment115846_48947), but that would be too extreme even for me).

```spl
A Happy Birth Day

Ajax, a hero
Ford, a man

          Act I: 1

          Scene I: 1

[Enter Ajax and Ford]

Ajax:
 You are nothing!

          Scene II: 2

Ford:
 Am I nicer than the sum of a big cow and a son?

Ajax:
 If so, we shall go to Scene V. You are as big as the sum of thyself and a cat!

          Scene III: 3

Ford:
 You are as red as the sum of a big red warm rich bold fair cat and a big rich fine son.
 Speak thy mind! You are as big as the sum of thyself and the sum of a cute fair fine
 rich cat and a hog! Speak thy mind! You are as big as the sum of thyself and the sum
 of a cute fair fine rich cat and a hog. Speak thy mind. Speak thy mind! You are as bold as
 the sum of thyself and the sum of a big fine fair cat and a cow. Speak thy mind! You are
 as big as a red old fair fine tiny cow. Speak thy mind! You are as old as the sum of
 thyself and the sum of a red old fair fine tiny cow and a big joy. Speak thy mind.
 You are as red as the sum of thyself and the sum of the sum of a red old fair fine
 tiny cow and a rich old red sky and a pig. Speak thy mind! You are as old as the sum
 of thyself and the sum of a big fine fair joy and a son. Speak thy mind. You are as
 red as the sum of thyself and a cute son. Speak thy mind! You are as cute as the sum
 of thyself and the sum of a bad fat vile pig and a fat bad lie. Speak thy mind! You are
 as fat as the sum of thyself and a vile evil war. Speak thy mind! You are as vile as the
 sum of thyself and the sum of a pig and a toad. Speak thy mind! You are as fair as the
 sum of thyself and the sum of a big fair hard fine son and a red fine fair joy. Speak
 thy mind! Are you as old as a big cow?

Ajax:
 If so, we shall go to Scene IV.

Ford:
 You are as big as a red old fair fine tiny cow. Speak thy mind! You are as old as the sum
 of thyself and the sum of the sum of a big red warm rich bold fair cat and a red old fair
 fine tiny cow and a bad hog. Speak thy mind! You are as big as the sum of thyself and the
 sum of a fat bad hog and a war. Speak thy mind! You are as big as a red old fair fine tiny
 cow. Speak thy mind! You are as old as the sum of thyself and the sum of a big red warm
 rich bold fair cat and a fat foul bad hog and a son. Speak thy mind. You are as fat as
 the sum of thyself and the sum of the sum of a big fair hard fine son and a big fine
 fair joy and a bad pig. Speak thy mind. 

Ajax:
 Let us return to Scene II.

          Scene IV: 4

Ford:
 You are as big as a red old fair fine tiny cow. Speak thy mind! You are as old as the
 sum of thyself and a big red warm rich bold fair cat and a warm sky. Speak thy mind.
 You are as fat as the sum of thyself and the sum of a red old fair fine tiny cow and a
 cat. Speak thy mind. You are as fat as the sum of thyself and a bad foul hog. Speak
 thy mind. You are as cute as the sum of thyself and the sum of a big fair hard fine
 son and a sky. Speak thy mind. You are as big as a red old fair fine tiny cow. Speak thy
 mind! You are as old as the sum of thyself and the sum of thyself and the sum of the sum
 of the sum of a red old fair fine tiny cow and a big fair hard fine son and a big joy and
 a son. Speak thy mind. You are as bad as the sum of thyself and the sum of a fat pig and a
 hog. Speak thy mind. You are as fat as the sum of thyself and a lazy pig. Speak thy mind.

Ajax:
 Let us return to Scene II.

          Scene V: 5

[Exeunt]
```

#### The meaning of all this?

OK, if you're curious about how all of this is supposed to work, let me try and explain my reasoning.
Firstly, the variables. They have to come from Shakesperian plays and, since tharacter count is important, we have to choose the small ones; thus, `Ajax` and `Ford` appear. They need a description after being declared (which is ignored, but still); I could've used a single letter, but heh.

#### Act I, Scene I

`var Ajax, Ford;
Ford = 0;`

We bring the variables into the stage and make `Ajax` tell `Ford` that his value will be 0.

#### Act I, Scene II

`if (Ford > 2*1+1)
    goto Scene V;
Ford = Ford + 1;`

OK, if the value stored in `Ford` is bigger than 3, the program jumps to Scene V; otherwhise, its value is incremented.

#### Act I, Scene III

`Ford = 2*2*2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*1-1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*1-1;
print((char) Ford);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*1+1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = 2*2*2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*1+(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*1+1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*(-1)+2*2*(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*(-1)+(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
if (Ajax == 2*1)
    goto Scene IV;
Ford = 2*2*2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*2*2*1+2*(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*(-1)+(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = 2*2*2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*(-1)+1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*1+2*(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*1+2*-1;
print((char) Ford);
goto Scene II;`

Loads and loads of lines. The idea is to fiddle with the value stored on `Ford`, doing loads and loads of arithmetic operations in order to get the ASCII number of the desired letters, then we tell the compiler to output the number in character form. That's how you write `Happy Birthday`.
There's an `if` inside this scene: the idea is to check if this is the third phrase of the song; if it is, we jump to Scene IV; otherwise we keep on forward, to write `to You`. After that, we jump back to Scene II.

#### Act I, Scene IV

`Ford = 2*2*2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*2*2*1+2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*2*1+1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*1+1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = 2*2*2*2*2*1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*2*2*2*1+2*2*2*2*1+2*1+1;
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*(-1)+(-1);
print((char) Ford);
Ford = Ford+2*2*(-1);
print((char) Ford);
goto Scene II;`

The way this works is similar to the Scene above: the idea is to write `Dear SPL`.

#### Act I, Scene V

`End.`

Just like that.

I still haven't found any place where this can be tested, unfortunately...

Comment: I think you should be able to repeat words, like `fat fat fat fat cat`. Also, I use https://github.com/drsam94/Spl/blob/master/splc.py to compile my spl code.

Answer (score 21):

### APL (48)

```
↑1⌽'Happy birthday '∘,¨(3/⊂'to you'),⊂'dear APL'
```

Comment: Tested successfully at [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/)

Comment: Three bytes shorter: [`↑'Happy birthday '∘,¨⌽4⍴3⍴'to you' 'dear APL'`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2191%27Happy%20birthday%20%27%u2218%2C%A8%u233D4%u23743%u2374%27to%20you%27%20%27dear%20APL%27&run)

Comment: it takes fewer bytes than APL's own age :) http://www.dyalog.com/50-years-of-apl.htm

Answer (score 16):

### Ruby, 54 bytes

I just thought "Hey, there's no Ruby answer yet", but then one appeared a few seconds before this one. Oh well...

```
puts h="Happy Birthday to You",h,h[0,15]+"Dear Ruby",h
```

Answer (score 16):

### Any love for PHP? <s>61</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
$s="
Happy Birthday";echo$t="$s to You","$t$s Dear PHP$t";
```

[See it in action @ http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c519991be966a335c84d6bb135061435033d39ab)

Comment: Combine the assignment to $t with its first output: `$s="\nHappy Birthday";echo$t="$s to You","$t$s Dear PHP$t";`

Comment: @manatwork excellent suggestion, thanks!

Comment: No. There is no love for PHP. Ever.

Comment: Same number of bytes with short tags: `<?=$t=($s="\nHappy Birthday")." to You","$t$s Dear PHP$t"?>`

Comment: Actually, you could go shorter still by 1 character. `<?=$t=($s="\nHappy Birthday")." to You","$t$s Dear PHP$t";` The close PHP tags are unnecessary, but you would need a semi-colon.

Comment: @PaulSkinner That's awesome! Which version of PHP are you using? I cannot get it to compile :(

Comment: @FakeName but it's going to be my birthday in a few days :'(

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 5.5.27 and seems to be working fine for me. Odd.

Comment: @PaulSkinner Can you try sandboxing it? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That sandbox doesn't allow you to include PHP opening tags, so the best I can show is: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30b2df7ef31035851d7fb272f962ea755e5c3414

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Here you go: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qQnKXK

Comment: Replace the `\n` with an actual line break in order to save a char.

Comment: @Christoph Nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I just can't decide on just one language :/

## BrainBack: 68

```
4 ["Happy birthday ">2 ->![<0 "to You
"]<[<0 "Dear BrainBack
"]<1 -]
```

*BrainBack is a mix between BrainFuck and Forth, made for a [PCG challenge Mar 7, 2014](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23426/11290)*

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 79

```
{h|"Happy Birthday ">}{t|"to You
">}&h&t&h&t&h|"Dear Extended BrainFuck
">&h&t
```

*EBF's birthday is [Jul 16, 2010](https://code.google.com/p/ebf-compiler/source/detail?r=14&path=/trunk/ebf.ebf)*

## Scheme: 96

(R5RS, Racket, R6RS REPL)

```scm
(map(lambda(e)(display"Happy Birthday ")(display(if e "to You\n" "Dear Scheme\n")))'(1 1 #f 1))
```

*Scheme was born [Dec, 1975](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-349.pdf) (NB: PDF)*

## [Zozotez](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/): 96

```lisp
((:'R(\(l)(p'|Happy birthday |())(p(?(a l)'|to You|'|Dear Zozotez|))(?(d l)(R(d l)))))'(t t()t))
```

However, It feels more right doing this one in French (86):

```lisp
((:'A(\(l)(p'|Joyeux anniversaire|())(p(a l))(?(d l)(A(d l)))))'(, , | Zozotez,| |.|))
```

Output:

```
Joyeux anniversaire,
Joyeux anniversaire,
Joyeux anniversaire Zozotez,
Joyeux anniversaire.
```

*Zozotez' birthday is [Jul 19, 2011](https://code.google.com/p/zozotez/downloads/detail?name=zozotez-alpha-16.bf&can=1&q=#makechanges)*

Comment: +1 for "Happy birthday dear Extended Brainfuck", probably the most laborious language name here. And yet the program is a fraction of the size of the equivalent for the parent language. And for Zozotez, which does indeed sound better in French, though in general I don't much like the way the French squeeze the person's name into an identical line for this song.

Comment: In your Zozotez answer, it should be `Joyeux anniversaire à Zozotez`.

Comment: @BetaDecay According to my (French) wife it should be without such preposition. [French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyeux_anniversaire) agrees.

Answer (score 16):

## Deadfish (<strike>2610</strike> 2391 chars)

What's this? An output only challenge? Sound like it's a job for [Deadfish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish)!

```
iiisdsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddsdddddodddddodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddsdddddodddddodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioddddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioddddoiiioiioiiioiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddsdddddodddddodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiio
```

Unfortunately, because Deadfish only outputs integers, the code above outputs the ASCII representations of each character in the song.

If we use the specification that

> Errors are not acknowledged: the shell simply adds a newline
>   character!

then we can golf this down to 2391 chars:

```
iiisdsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddsdddddodddddodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiofdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddsdddddodddddodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiofdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioddddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioddddoiiioiioiiioiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddofddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddoddddddddddddddddddddddddsiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioiioddddddddddddoddddodddoiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddsdddddodddddodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddodddddddddddddddddddddddsiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiio
```

Note: Deadfish isn't *actually* my favourite language, but I couldn't resist :P. Also golfing in Deadfish is a fun puzzle on its own.

Comment: For certain values of "fun".

Answer (score 13):

### JS, 83 bytes

```
h="Happy Birthday to You\n",console.log(h,h,h.replace("to You\n","Dear")+" JS\n",h)
```

**or 79 bytes by @Ingo Bürk**

```
h="Happy Birthday ",t="to You\n",console.log(h+t,h+t,h+"Dear Javascript\n",h+t)
```

**or 71 bytes by @kapep**

```
console.log(a=(b="Happy Birthday ")+"to You\n",a,b+"Dear Javascript\n",a)
```

*or run on the console this page (42 bytes)*

```
eval($("#answer-39759 code:first").text())
```

Comment: 1. [removed due to your edit] 2. There is no language called "JS", it's called "Javascript". Since it has to be printed, this matters. 3. It's pretty common to use the shorter `prompt` for output since Javascript can't print to stdout anyway. 4. There is no need for the trailing `;`.

Comment: Fixed sorry @IngoBürk

Comment: Also, this is shorter: `h='Happy Birthday ',t='to You\n';console.log(h+t,h+t,h+'Dear Javascript\n',h+t)` (you can still use `prompt` to save even more)

Comment: LOL at the last code piece .. :D

Comment: @IngoBürk, if you change all `+` with `,` you can spare the space after “Birthday”. (That way you get  the same length as with my best: `console.log(['',t='to You\n',t,'Dear JavaScript\n',t].join('Happy Birthday '))`. So no need to suggest this one.)

Comment: 76: `t='to you\n';console.log(h='Happy birthday',t+h,t+h,'dear JavaScript\n'+h,t)`

Comment: 71: `console.log(a=(b="Happy Birthday ")+"to You\n",a,b+"Dear Javascript\n",a)`

Comment: alert instead console.log, needs 2 more brackets but shorter: `alert((t=(h="Happy Birthday ")+'to You\n')+t+h+'dear EcmaScript\n'+t)` 69

Comment: Unprotected `console.log` without hitting F12 in IE10-? Party's over. ;^) `alert` is probably better, though Crockford's going to be mad you didn't `browser:true` and `window.alert` it.

Answer (score 12):

## T-SQL, <s>89</s> 87 bytes

**Edit:** Probably shouldn't be dredging these old things up, but I just noticed an obvious change to this to reclaim a couple of bytes.

Using STUFF to remove unwanted parts of the string, the starting index is provided by the values in the `FROM` clause multiplied by 3

```
SELECT STUFF('Happy Birthday to You  Dear SQL',N,8,'')FROM(VALUES(24),(24),(15),(24))S(N)
```

Comment: This one is nice!

Comment: This is a brilliant SQL solution and a very nice trick!

Answer (score 11):

## R: 70 bytes

Takes advantage of `paste` and vector recycling.

```
writeLines(paste(rep("Happy Birthday",4),c(rep("to You",2),"Dear R")))
```

Comment: `cat(paste(rep("Happy Birthday",4),c(rep("to You",2),"Dear R"),'\n'))`

Comment: @germcd That doesn't quite work, since `cat` adds spaces between the strings. So you end up with a space at the beginning of each line except the first.

Comment: `write(x,"")` -> `write(paste(rep("Happy Birthday",4),c(rep("to You",2),"Dear R")),"")` 68 bytes. Here is my original solution with 73 `p=paste;write(c(i<-p(h<-"Happy Birthday","to You"),i,p(h,"Dear R"),i),"")` Vector recycling beats me again.

Comment: Reduced to 66 bytes `\`~\`=rep;write(paste("Happy Birthday"~4,c("to You"~2,"Dear R")),"")` https://tio.run/##K/r/P6EuwbYotcC6vCizJFWjILEYSCp5JBYUVCo4ZRaVZKQkVirVmegkayiV5CtE5pcq1RnpKLmkJhYpBClpauooKWn@/w8A

Answer (score 11):

## Python 507 bytes

```
print """
H  a     p     py-  Bir  t   h    day  -to-Y ou=  Happy -  B irt       h     d   a y
-  t    o -    Y  o u  =  H a     p  p   y   -  B   i   r  t h  d     a y     - D  e
ar-P   ython   =Ha  ppy    -      Bir    t   hda    y   -to- Y   o   uHapp     y   -
B  i  r     t  h    d      a      y  -   t   o -    Y   o  u =  H   a     p    p
y  - B       i r    t      h      day  -to-Y o  u   =   H  a ppy   -       B   i   r
""".replace("\n","").replace(" ","").replace("-"," ").replace("=","\n")[:92]
```

Not winning any prizes ... but if you look at it carefully, there is some ASCII art:

```
#  #     #     ###  ###  #   #    ###  ##### ###  ##### #  # ###       #     #   # #
#  #    # #    #  # #  #  # #     #  #   #   #  #   #   #  # #  #     # #     # #  #
####   #####   ###  ###    #      ###    #   ###    #   #### #   #   #####     #   #
#  #  #     #  #    #      #      #  #   #   # #    #   #  # #  #   #     #    #
#  # #       # #    #      #      ###  ##### #  #   #   #  # ###   #       #   #   #
```

Comment: This is not a serious contender.

Comment: @Challenger5 Yes, "However, I'm also rewarding other witty submissions with up-votes (and I encourage everybody to do so as well). Therefore although this is a code-golf contest, not-so-short answers are also welcome."

Answer (score 9):

## GNU dc, 51

```
[Happy Birthday to You]d[Happy Birthday Dear dc]rdf
```

Comment: I also tried with `dc`, but even the almost raw version is shorter: `[Happy Birthday To You]d[Happy Birthday Dear dc]rdf` 51 characters.

Comment: On a roll today @manatwork :)

Comment: I learned of the existence of dc today because of this post and it's excellent.

Answer (score 9):

## Perl - 58

```
say"Happy Birthday ".($_?"Dear Perl":"To You")for(0,0,1,0)
```

Run with:

```
perl -E'say"Happy Birthday ".($_?"Dear Perl":"To You")for(0,0,1,0)'
```

Just for fun:

```
perl -E'for(<HappyBirthday{0,1,2,3}>){s/B/ B/;s/2/ Dear Perl\n/;print s/\d/ To You\n/r}'
```

Comment: How about `say"Happy Birthday $_"for("to You","Dear Perl")[0,0,1,0]` ?

Comment: @core1024 I didn't know you could do that with arrays, that's awesome. Feel free to post as your own answer!

Answer (score 9):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>687</s> <s>686</s> <s>686</s></sub> 681 Bytes

From the problem statement:

> However, I'm also rewarding other witty submissions with up-votes (and I encourage everybody to do so as well). Therefore although this is a code-golf contest, not-so-short answers are also welcome.

### Code

Full `sub`routine that takes no input and outputs a happy birthday song for VBA onto the range `[A1:CM23]` of the `ActiveSheet` object.

```vb
Global l
Sub a
Cells.RowHeight=48
For l=0To 3
p[A1:A5,B3,C1:C5,F1,E2:E5,G2:G5,F3,I1:I5,J1,K2,J3,M1:M5,N1,O2,N3,Q1:Q2,R3:R5,S1:S2]
p[Y1:Y5,Z1,AA2,Z3,AA4,Z5,AC1:AE1,AD2:AD4,AC5:AE5,AG1:AG5,AH1,AI2,AH3,AI4:AI5,AK1:AM1,AL2:Al5,AO1:AO5,AP3,AQ1:AQ5,AS1:AS5,AT1,AU2:AU4,AT5,AX1,AW2:AW5,AY2:AY5,AX3,BA1:BA2,BB3:BB5,BC1:BC2]
If l-2Then p[BI1:BK1,BJ2:BJ5,BN1,BM2:BM4,BN5,BO2:BO4,BU1:BU2,BV3:BV5,BW1:BW2,BZ1,BY2:BY4,BZ5,CA2:CA4,CC1:CC4,CD5,CE1:CE5]Else p[BI1:BI5,BJ1,BK2:BK4,BJ5,BM1:BM5,BN1:BO1,BN3,BN5:BO5,BR1,BQ2:BQ5,BS2:BS5,BR3,BU1:BU5,BV1,BW2,BV3,BW4:BW5,CC1:CC4,CD5,CE1:CE4,CG1:CG5,CH1,CI2,CH3,CI4,CH5,CL1,CK2:CK5,CM2:CM5,CL3]
Next
End Sub
Sub p(r)
r.Offset(6*l).Interior.Color=0
End Sub
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer, +1

Answer (score 7):

## PowerShell - <s>69</s> <s>64</s> 59

```
1,1,0,1|%{"Happy Birthday "+("Dear $ShellId","To You")[$_]}
```

and 91

```
$a,$b,$c="Happy Birthday.To You.Dear PowerShell".Split(".");1..2|%{"$a $b"};"$a $c";"$a $b"
```

and 108

```
$a=@();$b,$c="To You.Dear PowerShell".Split(".");1..4|%{$a+="Happy Birthday $b"};$a[2]=$a[2]-replace$b,$c;$a
```

Comment: `"Dear $ShellId"`. That made me smile.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 56

```ruby
x="Happy Birthday To You
"*4
x[59,6]="Dear Ruby"
puts x
```

Comment: Can't you inline things ?

Comment: A method ending in `=` always returns the result of the expression after the equals sign. If I inlined this, it'd only print `"Dear Ruby"` (`String#[]=` is a method).

Comment: >Newlines in strings. Okay, now i'm completely convinced that ruby is just voodoo magic and as a peasant I should stick to python instead.

Answer (score 6):

## Var'aQ - 121

```
"Happy Birthday " ~ a cher "to you\n" tlheghrar ~ b cher b tlheghrar a "dear Var'aQ" tlheghrar tlheghrar b tlheghrar cha'
```

Comment: Qapla'!

+1 for using Var'aQ of all languages!

Comment: Would be better if you translated the song to Klingon too :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/), 151

Prints `Happy Birthday` every time `hb` is called, with either `to you` or `Dear Marbelous` appended, based on whether the input is `0` or `1`. The passed marble in `hb` will not be outputted, as it will get stuck in the synchroniser `&0`.

```
03
00
02
01
hb
:hb
}0
=0&0
&1
&2//
746F20596F7544656172204D617262656C6F75730A
&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2
486170707920426972746864617920
```

Below is the board `hb`, with hex converted to ascii text:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, 46 bytes

```
4,{"Happy Birthday "\2="Dear CJam""to You"?N}%
```

[Try it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

```
4,                                             "Push [0,1,2,3].";
  {                                         }% "Map...";
   "Happy Birthday "                           "Push the string.";
                    \                          "Swap top two stack elements (string and
                                                array element)";
                     2=                        "Check equality with 2.";
                       "Dear CJam""to You"     "Push two more strings.";
                                          ?    "Select string based on result of 2=.";
                                           N   "Push a line break";
```

This leaves the following array on the stack:

```
["Happy Birthday " "to You" "\n" "Happy Birthday " "to You" "\n" "Happy Birthday " "Dear CJam" "\n" "Happy Birthday " "to You" "\n"]
```

Whose contents are automatically printed back-to-back at the end of the program.

Alternatively, with a for-loop and the same character count:

```
4{"Happy Birthday "I2="Dear CJam""to You"?N}fI
```

Comment: Liar!! your favorite language is Ruby/Mathematica :P

Comment: @Optimizer Certainly not Ruby, maybe Mathematica, but I'm not even sure about that. For "real" programming I'd probably always choose C/C++/C#. (I'm also pretty sure, that yours is JS :P.)

Comment: you got me :P :D

Answer (score 5):

## GolfScript: 54 characters

```
4,{"Happy Birthday "["To You""Dear GolfScript"]@2==n}%
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ golfscript.rb <<< '4,{"Happy Birthday "["To You""Dear GolfScript"]@2==n}%'
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear GolfScript
Happy Birthday To You
```

Comment: I just noticed it. (Little side effect of trying to write that GolfScript code for about 5~6 hours.) Thanks, @MartinBüttner.

Comment: Happy Birthday Dear *CodeGolf*?

Comment: Grr. I was tired not only when wrote it, but also when fixed it. Thanks @Dennis.

Answer (score 5):

### T-SQL (MS compliant): 75

```
print stuff(replicate('Happy Birthday to You '+char(10),4),62,6,'Dear SQL')
```

Comment: Nice one ... wish I had thought of that:)

Comment: Great idea! Save 9 more bytes by replacing `+char(10)` with a line break inside the quote, just make the return part of the string.

Answer (score 5):

## **C# <strike>(75)</strike> (73)**

Using `System.Diagnostics` for the purpose of `Debug.Print`

Upgrade to @Abbas' code

```
string x="\nHappy Birthday ",y=x+"to You";Debug.Print(y+y+x+"Dear C#"+y);
```

Upgrade to @Tyress' code **<strike>(83)</strike> (76)**

```
for(int i=0;i++<4;)Debug.Print("Happy Birthday "+(i!=3?"to You":"Dear C#"));
```

Output:

```
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear C#
Happy Birthday To You
```

Comment: You can save a couple characters using `String.Format` and the ternary operator. You can also make this look much less like a C# program and use `i++<3` ;p

Answer (score 5):

## Retina, 47 <s>49</s> <s>50</s> <s>52</s> bytes

The program is encoded as ISO-8559-1 (which the official interpreter accepts). The leading newline is significant.

```
¶¶x¶

Happy Birthday to You
.{27}u
Dear Retina
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CsK2wrZ4wrYKCkhhcHB5IEJpcnRoZGF5IHRvIFlvdQouezI3fXUKRGVhciBSZXRpbmE&input=)

## Explanation

Step 1: Replace the (empty) input with “newline, newline, x, newline”.

Step 2: In between every character, insert `Happy Birthday to You`. We now have:

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to YouxHappy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
```

Step 3: replace a 28-character string ending in `u` and not containing a newline with `Dear Retina`. The only occurrence of that is `to YouxHappy Birthday to You`.

Answer (score 5):

## Reng, 66 bytes

Noncompeting.

```
A"uoY ot yadhtriB yppaH"¤ao;A"gneR raeD yadhtriB yppaH ~"S0gO0gao;
```

Simple enough. `A` is 10, or a newline. `"uoY ot yadhtriB yppaH"` pushes that string, `¤` duplicates the string, `ao;` outputs everything. The second part is more interesting. `"A"gneR raeD yadhtriB yppaH ~"` pushes that string. `S` pushes 28, and `0g` sets the character at (0, 28) to the top of stack, or a `~`, the end program signal. This sets the last `A` to a tilde. Then, `O0g` sets the character at`(0, 24)` to a space/nop, removing the duplicate stack command. We print the third line using `ao;`. Then, we wrap around to the beginning of the line and print the last line again.

Here's a GIF, because who doesn't like those?

[image: GIIIIF]

Answer (score 5):

## 05AB1E, 36 bytes

```
”ŽØ¢©”©" to You"«Ð®" Dear 05AB1E"«s»
```

[TIO Nexus](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYe7RvYdnHFp0aCWQeWilkkJJvkJkfqnSodWHJxxap6TgkppYpGBg6uhk6AoUKz60@/9/AA)

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdxb3DmMKiwqnigJ3CqSIgdG8gWW91IsKrw5DCriIgRGVhciAwNUFCMUUiwqtzwrs&input=)

**Output:**

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear 05AB1E
Happy Birthday to You
```

**Explanation:**

```
”ŽØ¢©”                                Push "Happy Birthday"
                                       STACK: ["Happy Birthday"]
      ©                               Store in register w/o popping
       " to You"«                     Append " to You"
                                       STACK: ["Happy Birthday to You"]
                 Ð                    Triplicate the string
                                       STACK: ["Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You"]
                  ®                   Push "Happy Birthday" from register
                                       STACK: ["Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday"]
                   " Dear 05AB1E"«    Append " Dear 05AB1E"
                                       STACK: ["Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday Dear 05AB1E"]
                                  s   Swap top two strings
                                       STACK: ["Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday to You", "Happy Birthday Dear 05AB1E", "Happy Birthday to You"]
                                   »  Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java, <s>127</s> 125 bytes

```
class h{public static void main(String[]a){String b="\nHappy Birthday ",d=b+"to You";System.out.print(d+d+b+"Dear Java"+d);}}
```

However, if you ignore all of the excess stuff, it is only <s>82</s> 80 bytes:

```
String b="\nHappy Birthday ",d=b+"to You";System.out.print(d+d+b+"Dear Java"+d);
```

Oh, and it starts with a newline, saving 2 bytes.

Comment: output is not exactly as required, since there's an extra line at the start

Comment: @Supuhstar It merely says to output the song happy birthday. It makes no requirement for excess newlines/whitespace.

Comment: it says "writes the following text to the standard output or an arbitrary file:"... so... maybe you could stretch that to include extra bits? It doesn't sound like this is the intended answer, though.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but System.out.println is a standard output.

Comment: I don't mean the output _method_, but the actual output, which starts with a blank line

Answer (score 4):

## BBC BASIC, 81 / 76 ASCII characters

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

Unfortunately, it's not possible to choose between strings within an expression, so the line endings are repetitively encoded in a `DATA` statement. On the other hand, when you read the last line, it does sound quite musical.

```
FORk=1TO4READa$PRINT"Happy Birthday ";a$:NEXT 
DATAto You,to You,Dear BASIC,to You
```

We can, however, choose what substring to select from a given string, for a saving of 5 characters (note that `k=3` evaluates to `-1` when true):

```
FORk=1TO4PRINT"Happy Birthday ";MID$("Dear BASICto You",11+(k=3)*10,10):NEXT
```

## BBC BASIC, 69 ASCII characters

A shorter way:

```
a$="Happy Birthday "b$="to You"PRINTa$;b$'a$;b$'a$;"dear BASIC"'a$;b$
```

Comment: I had no idea that you didn't need a colon for one-liners...

Comment: @BetaDecay according to the official syntax you do need the colon in most cases. But in practice BBC BASIC for Windows lets you get away without them. The original BBC Micro manual gave certain advice for improving the speed of your programs, of which I've taken in the following: use lowercase variable names, and eliminate as many unnecesary characters as possible.

Answer (score 4):

### J (44)

```
2|.'Happy birthday ',"1'dear J',>3#<'to you'
```

Answer (score 4):

### Groovy (64)

```
4.times{println"Happy Birthday ${it==2?'Dear Groovy':'to You'}"}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Common Lisp (<del>62</del> 60 chars)

```
(format t"~@{Happy Birthday ~[to You~;dear CL~]~%~}"0 0 1 0)
```

## Output

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday dear CL
Happy Birthday to You
```

Comment: Is the space before and after the string needed?

Comment: @Kay No, the space is not needed. I removed it, which saves 2 chars. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## VBA 99

Why VBA? Why not?

```
Sub H(): For i = 0 To 3: MsgBox "Happy Birthday " & IIf(i = 2, "Dear VBA", "to You"): Next: End Sub
```

Ungolfed

```
Sub H()
    For i = 0 To 3
        MsgBox "Happy Birthday " & IIf(i = 2, "Dear VBA", "to You")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Still shorter than C# :D

Comment: For what it's worth (2.5yrs later), you can remove the auto-formatting to get it down to 86 bytes: `Sub H():For i=0To 3:MsgBox"Happy Birthday " &IIf(i=2,"Dear VBA","to You"):Next:End Sub`

Comment: @EngineerToast I don't feel like that's legit. The only environment that compiles that code enforces those spaces.

Comment: I used to think that, too, so I did some searching on meta and found [a post that made sense to me](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10259/38183) saying why autoformatting should be discounted. It's not *wrong* either way but I somewhat enjoy finding all the white space I can remove from VBA and have it still work.

Comment: @EngineerToast I'll actually buy that, because the official grammar doesn't require the white space.

Answer (score 4):

## Casio CFX-9850G, 121 bytes <del>96</del>

Just for the fun of it, the Happy Birthday song for the CFX-9850G graphing calculator.

Some instructions are just displayed as multiple bytes, but as far as I know they are encoded as 1 or 2 bytes. I marked them with colors.
Edit: I checked the memory, so the program uses 121 bytes in the calculator.

The song text would not fit in a line, especially line 3 because in text mode the calculator can only display 7 rows and 21 columns. So I print the lyrics in graphing mode, which uses a tiny font.

[image: Happy Birthday, CFX-9850G. Program]

Here is the output:

[image: Happy Birthday CFX-9850G. Output]

Answer (score 4):

**Qt 5.4 qmake pro file, 119 bytes**

Since the winner has already been announced, I thought I'd give a try for the *witty* category.

```
O=$$escape_expand(\n)
A=Happy Birthday
B=$$A to you$$O
CONFIG(debug,debug|release){log($$A dear qmake$$O)}log($$B)
```

This abuses **qmake** horribly.

qmake under default settings will parse a script 3 times over. For debug, release, and a build_pass. So we just let it throw out the "Happy Birthday" for all logs, with an extra "To you..." when a debug makefile is being generated.

```
Happy Birthday to you
Happy Birthday to you
Happy Birthday dear qmake
Happy Birthday to you
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>74</s> 73

```js
for(i=5;--i;)console.log('Happy birthday',i-2?'to you':'dear JavaScript')
```

Thanks to Dancrumb for the byte-saving tip. It would be <s>68</s> 67 bytes if I could use 4 `alert`s instead of newlines.

```js
for(i=5;--i;)alert('Happy birthday',i-2?'to you':'dear JavaScript')
```

Comment: You can shave off a byte with: `for(i=5;--i;)console.log('Happy birthday',i-2?'to you':'dear JavaScript')`

Comment: If you want `alert()`, then use only 1, based on [my comment at the other JavaScript answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/sing-happy-birthday-to-your-favourite-programming-language/39764#comment91050_39759). That will be 71 character without `alert()` flood.

Comment: You could also avoid the loops and let the output just be the expression itself (which is true on newer consoles): `(a="\nHappy Birthday")&&(b=a+" to You")&&b+b+a+" Dear JavaScript"+a` (67 too).

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 593 characters

Used [this](http://a-varun.github.io/brain_fcuk/index.html)

```
++++++++++[>+>+++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++<<<<<<<<<-]>>>>++.>>+++++++.>>++..>+.<<<<<<<++.>++++++.>>>>+++++.>++.++.<-.----.<.>>>.<<<<<<<.>>>>>>.-----.<<<<<<.>>>+++++++++.>>>.++++++.<<<<<<<.>>>.>>.>>-----..>.<<<<<<<.>.>>>>+++++.>++.++.<-.----.<.>>>.<<<<<<<.>>>>>>.-----.<<<<<<.>>>.>>>.++++++.<<<<<<<.>>>.>>.>>-----..>.<<<<<<<.>.>>>>+++++.>++.++.<-.----.<.>>>.<<<<<<<.>++.>>>>+.<.>>--.<<<<<<.>--.>>>>>.<<.>++++.>----.<---.>+++++++.<<++.>+++++.<<<<<<.>>>.>>--.>>-----..>.<<<<<<<.>.>>>>--.>++.++.<-.----.<.>>>.<<<<<<<.>>>>>>.-----.<<<<<<.>>>.>>>.++++++.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Powershell one liner: <del>73</del> 71**

`1..4|%{"Happy Birthday $(if($_-eq3){"Dear Powershell"}else{"to You"})"}`

Comment: You could shrink this to 71 if you did `$_-eq3`

Answer (score 3):

## Swift, 83

Run this in Xcode Playground

```
let h="\nhappy birthday"
let t=" to you"
let f=h+t+h+t+h+" dear Swift"+h+t
print(f)
```

Comment: If you put the space after `happy birthday`, you can get rid of the two in `to you` and `dear Swift`, saving you one byte

Comment: If you declare all 3 variables on the same line, you can save 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 96 bytes

I was trying to be cool about this and make use of all the best Lua tricks I know but the guy who wrote a simple for loop with an `if i==3` beat me by 20+ bytes >.<

Still, I think this is pretty cool in terms of Golfing:

```
a='Happy Birthday to you\ndear Lua\n'print(a:sub(0,-10):rep(3):sub(0,-8)..a:rep(2):sub(23,-10))
```

I was looking at recursively building the string `a` from a number using string.char() but I couldn't compress it anywhere near the length of `a='Happy Birthday to you\ndear Lua\n'`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), <strike>90</strike> 45 bytes

```
i
Happy Birthday to you
[ESC]
yypppPWWd$adear Vim
```

90 chars version:

```
i
Happy Birthday to you dear Vim
[ESC]
:%s/\(.* .* \)(.. .*\) \(.* .*\)/\1\2\r\1\2\r\1\3\r\1\2
```

I'm certain there is a quicker way but this is what I just came up with :)

Puts out

```
Happy Birthday to you
Happy Birthday to you
Happy Birthday dear Vim
Happy Birthday to you
```

Answer (score 3):

**APL: 45**

```
4 23⍴'Dear APL',⍨61⍴'Happy birthday to you  '
```

**Explanation:**

61⍴ reapeats the string up to length 61, after which "Dear APL" is concatenated (,)

Note that ⍨ inverts arguments, so it's added at the end.

4 23⍴ just makes a matrix 4x23 using the string on the right, starting from the beginning of the string each time it reaches the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 42

```
V4+"Happy Birthday "?"to You"nN2"Dear Pyth
```

Demonstration:

```
$ pyth -c 'V4+"Happy Birthday "?"to You"nN2"Dear Pyth'
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear Pyth
Happy Birthday to You
```

How it works:

`V4` sets up a for loop, with N iterating over `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Then, we create the string starting with `"Happy Birthday "`, and ending with `"to You"` if `N` does not equal `2` (`nN2` calculates this), or ending with `"Dear Pyth"` otherwise.

Exact tie with CJam - language name and character count.

---

Alternative, 43 character solution:

```
J"Happy Birthday to You"JJ+<J15"Dear Pyth"J
```

It's one character longer because it needs an end quote.

Comment: Aren't the `V` and `N` implemented after the question was asked ?

Comment: @Optimizer No, they were added a while ago. Looking back at the commit log, they were added on August 21st, in a commit called:
`Pyth 2.1.0 - Changes to -;\AcPUVXz`
Out of curiosity, what gave you that impression?

Comment: Your recent Pyth tips answer left me thinking that it is something new and u always keep saying that you keep on adding features :).

Comment: @Optimizer Ah - while I do add new things, I'm also trying to give general programming tips on that page, which cover everything in Pyth.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <del>75</del> <del>67</del> 65 characters

<del>`a,b,c="Happy Birthday ","To You\n","Dear Julia\n";print("$a$b$a$b$a$c$a$b")`</del>

<del>`a="Happy Birthday";b=("$a To You\n");print("$b$b$a Dear Julia\n$b")`</del>

`a="Happy Birthday To You\n";print("$a$a$(a[1:15])Dear Julia\n$a")`

Just for fun, here is an ungolfed version, with a loop (114 characters):

```
for i = 1:4
    a,b,c = "Happy Birthday ","To You","Dear Julia"
    i != 3 ? println("$a$b") : println("$a$c")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 42 bytes

```
0000000: f3 48 2c 28 a8 54 70 ca 2c 2a c9 48 49 ac  .H,(.Tp.,*.HI.
000000e: 54 28 c9 57 88 cc 2f e5 22 4a d4 25 35 b1  T(.W../."J.%5.
000001c: 48 c1 a9 34 29 29 27 35 bd 34 17 bb 1e 00  H..4))'5.4....
```

Note that this answer is non-competing, since Bubblegum is a lot younger than this challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fishing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fishing), 116 bytes

```
v+CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
  `Happy Birthday `P{`to You`N}P{N}P{{`Dear Fishing`N}}P{N
```

Comment: I've posted a few questions, but here's my first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Seriously, <s>59</s> 57 bytes (non-competitive)

`"Happy Birthday to You";"Happy Birthday Dear Seriously"@;`

**Explanation**

Push "Happy Birthday to You", duplicate, push "Happy Birthday Dear Seriously", rotate the two top elements, duplicate, and implicit popping and printing.

Comment: 57 bytes: `"Happy Birthday to You";"Happy Birthday Dear Seriously"@;`

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 48 bytes

```
/U/Happy Birthday //T/Uto You/T
T
UDear \/\/\/
T
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>41</s> 38 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`Happy Bir»y  Y
`
³h58Ui` De Japt
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YEhhcHB5IEJpcpC7eSCRIFmMCmAKs2g1OFVpYCBEZYcgSmFwdAo)

Answer (score 3):

### Underload, 59 Bytes

```
(to You
):(Happy Birthday ):S~S:S~:S~:S(Dear Underload
)SSS
```

I was hindered by Underload's lack of stack manipulation commands. I had to push stuff in a strange order and swap a bit more than I would have preferred, but oh well...

Stack trace:

```
(...) | (to You)
:     | (to You)(to You)
(...) | (to You)(to You)(Happy Birthday )
:S    | (to You)(to You)(Happy Birthday )         ; output "Happy Birthday "
~     | (to You)(Happy Birthday )(to You)
S     | (to You)(Happy Birthday )                 ; output "to You"
:S    | (to You)(Happy Birthday )                 ; output "Happy Birthday "
~     | (Happy Birthday )(to You)
:S    | (Happy Birthday )(to You)                 ; output "to You"
~     | (to You)(Happy Birthday )
:S    | (to You)(Happy Birthday )                 ; output "Happy Birthday "
(...) | (to You)(Happy Birthday )(Dear Underload)
S     | (to You)(Happy Birthday )                 ; output "Dear Underload"
S     | (to You)                                  ; output "Happy Birthday "
S     |                                           ; output "to You
```

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 135 bytes

**Great thanks to Steadybox and DJMcMayhem for shortening this code by 55 characters! :)**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
std::string s="Happy Birthday ",t="to you\n",u="Dear C++\n";int main(){std::cout<<s+t+s+t+s+u+s+t;}
```

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `<<`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can remove the space from between `#include` and `<headerName>`. Also, you can declare the strings in one go so you don't have to repeat the `string`. (After that using the `std::` prefix is shorter than `using namespace std;`, too). [Like this.](https://tio.run/##PYxBDsIgEEX3PcVk3GjAC7TQhbrwEG4IkDqJBQJDk8Z4djSauvl57y2@Tek4WdvajoJ9VOcVxcLZm3ns/ukTKExjV9j1/U@gaLyalFY4Uea7MyugZI0cYY0VZdV48SbDWQiUi8ZbwIECw2wo7A/P75ONlZUqgsUitq0bD6/W3g)

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 98 bytes

```
fn main(){for i in range(0i,4){println!("Happy birthday {}",match i{2=>"dear Rust",_=>"to you"})}}
```

Comment: Suggest `0..4` instead of `range(0i,4)`

Comment: @ceilingcat: And swap `match` for `if...else`, use `print!`,neglect `fn main`: 78 bytes https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZ/T8tv0ghUyEzT8FAT8@kuqAoM69EUUPJI7GgoFIhKbOoJCMlsVKhupZLSSczTSHT1taoWiklNbFIIQhojlJtak5xarVSSb5CZX6pUq1m7X9rrloqGwkA

Answer (score 2):

## Lua: <del>91</del> 72 characters

First pass:

```
for i=1,4 do io.write'Happy Birthday 'if i==3 then print'Dear Lua'else print'to You'end end
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/6hXxzUjP)

Even smaller:

```
for i=1,4 do print('Happy Birthday '..(i==3 and'Dear Lua'or'to You'))end
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/FmQKv0GR)

## TI-BASIC: 65

```
:PROGRAM:H
:"HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO YOU
:Disp Ans,Ans,sub(Ans,1,15)+"DEAR TI-BASIC
:Disp Ans
```

In TI-BASIC, all built-in commands (even multi letter ones) are either one or two bytes on the calculator. The size I used represents the (minimum, since names take space) space taken by this code on my TI-84+SE running OS version 2.53MP.
Seemingly wrong syntax (unclosed strings) is intentional.

## TI-68k: 90

```
:h()
:Prgm
:"Happy Birthday to You"→a
:Disp a,a,mid(a,1,15)&"Dear TI-68k",a
:EndPrgm
```

Again, the size I used is the minimum real size on the calc (in this case, a TI-92).

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 89 bytes (also it is not my favourite)

```
(1 to 4).map{i=>"Happy Birthday "+(if(i==3)"dear SCALA" else "to You")}.foreach{println}
```

Maybe it could be less, it is just a default example, so feel free to improve.

**Regarding Java:**

If ignoring the excess stuff it is also possible to do a "import static java.lang.System.*;" and then use out.println. So something like this is possible (87 chars):

```
int i=0;while(i<=3){out.println("Happy Birthday "+((i==2)?"dear Java":"to you"));i++;}
```

(also it is longer than the solution from Stretch Maniac - see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39768)

Comment: Aww, it's too bad Scala isn't your favorite. [Here's](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nmLAV00oQ62MGawpFQMRsQ) 2 more ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 69 chars

```
for(i in 1:4)cat('Happy Birthday',ifelse(i==3,'Dear R','to You'),'\n')
```

Or

```
for(i in 1:4)cat('Happy Birthday',if(i==3)'Dear R' else 'to You','\n')
```

All output:

```
Happy Birthday to You 
Happy Birthday to You 
Happy Birthday Dear R 
Happy Birthday to You
```

Otherwise with 66 characters there was, without the `for` loop:

```
a=rep('to You',4);a[3]='Dear R';cat(paste('Happy Birthday',a,'\n'))
```

But it outputs:

```
Happy Birthday to You 
 Happy Birthday to You 
 Happy Birthday Dear R 
 Happy Birthday to You
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#

**LINQPad (69):**

```
string x="\nHappy Birthday ",y=x+"to You";(y+y+x+"Dear C#"+y).Dump();
```

**Console (75):**

```
string x="\nHappy Birthday ",y=x+"to You";Console.Write(y+y+x+"Dear C#"+y);
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
string x = "\nHappy Birthday ";
string y = x + "to You";

//LINQPad
(y + y + x + "Dear C#" + y).Dump(); 

//Console
Console.Write(y+y+x+"Dear C#"+y);
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP <del>67</del> <del>63</del> 62

```
echo$z=($s="Happy Birthday").$t=" to You
","$z$s Dear PHP
$z";
```

EDIT:
As @manatwork pointed out, without the second echo I have 4 chars less!!

EDIT2:
Other improvement according to @manatwork

Comment: Nice one. But you not need a separate `echo` to have the earlier set variables available. Make the 2nd line: `","$z${s}Dear PHP`.

Comment: @manatwork great suggestion!

Comment: You can spare 1 more character by getting rid of those braces around variable `${s}`. If you add the middle space to the both second half lines instead of the first half line, the length increases by 1 character, but you will be able to remove the braces, sparing 2 characters: http://pastebin.com/Qw7dWHGs

Comment: @manatwork I didn't got this... If I add the middle space to both the second half lines (before "to You" and before "Dear PHP") then I'm adding 2 chars and removing the brackets I have the same count

Comment: Now: "Happy_" + "You" + "Dear", proposed : "Happy" + "_You" + "_Dear". So actually one of them you move and add just one new.

Comment: @manatwork genius!

Answer (score 2):

### Visual FoxPro - 77

Not really my favorite language, but makes golfing somewhat interesting. Here is my greetings to it:

```
a="Happy Birthday "
b="to You"
?a+b
?a+b
?a+"Dear "+_screen.Caption
?a+b
```

This abuses the fact that `_screen.Caption` (the main window title) initially contains *Microsoft Visual FoxPro*, handy here. If I'm allowed to call the language by its "friendly name", I can just replace that for "Fox" and save 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell 62

```
0..3|%{"Happy Birthday "+("to You","Dear PowerShell")[$_-eq2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica (65)**

```
Print["Happy Birthday "<>#]&/@{s="to you",s,"dear Mathematica",s}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! As this is a code golf challenge, please add the byte count of your code next to the language name.

Answer (score 2):

## Delphi, <strike>154</strike> <strike>146</strike> 139

```
uses{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}SysUtils,StrUtils;var i:byte;begin
for i:=0to 3do WriteLn('Happy birthday '+IfThen(i=2,'dear Delphi','to you'))end.
```

Comment: Which Delphi version is this? I never met one with such `Output` parameter. And better choose another integer type, with a shorter name. For example `Byte`.

Comment: An insignificant bug: the 'to you' and 'dear Delphi' should be reversed.

Comment: Some minor shortening which work in FreePascal: move the directive between `uses` and the first unit name to be able to remove the space (1 char); remove unnecessary newline characters (3 chars); remove the `;` before `end` (1 char); remove the space characters between numeric literals and the following keywords (2 chars). See whether any of those works in your Delphi too.

Comment: @manatwork, thank you for your suggestions, it's Delphi XE2.

Comment: There's no need for `Output,`.

Answer (score 2):

### C (74 characters)

```
main(i){for(i=4;i;)printf("Happy birthday %s\n",i---2?"to You":"Dear C");}
```

### Python 2 (72 characters)

```
for k in range(4):print"Happy birthday",k==2 and"Dear Python"or"to You"
```

Python 3 would need parentheses around the printed string, so two character more, so 74.

### PHP (66 characters)

```
for($i=4;$i;)echo"Happy birthday ".($i---2?"to You\n":"Dear PHP\n");
```

Comment: In C, `i---2` saves a character. Also `{}` after `for` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

## TeX - 70

```
\def\h{Happy Birthday }\def\y{to You}\h\y

\h\y

\h Dear TeX

\h\y\bye
```

Note that the line breaks are intentional and actually required.

Answer (score 2):

## LaTeX, 182

This isn't intended to be a serious competitive entry, but just to do something fun. Therefore, disregard the char count. I don't need any golfing tips for this, because it is intentionally ungolfed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\h}[1]{Happy Birthday to {#1}}
\newcommand{\g}{\h{You}}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\g \\
\g \\
\h{\LaTeX} \\
\g \\
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Cardinal, <del>113</del> <del>107</del> <del>88</del> 82 characters

I fixed the errors in the original interpreter, so the operators work as specified. This enabled me to shrink down the code by another <del>19</del> 25 characters:

4th version:

```
v8888#;++"lanidraC raeD " <
8%+++>>"Happy Birthday"-jv^
>8888@^        ;"uoY oT "<
```

Output, using my interpreter fixes:

```
Executing program..

Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear Cardinal
Happy Birthday To You

Execution complete.
>
```

Second version, saving 6 chars:
I changed the o’s and O’s to v^<> because the available interpreter has some errors with the handling of the rotation operators o and O, j and J and some other errors. One has to use the wrong rotation operators to make it work, but I prefer using a version that works according to specification. The length of the code stays the same.
This version works properly with the interpreter provided at the link given at the bottom of my comment:
(107 characters)

```
%->"Happy Birthd"v
x ^D+;"uoY oT ya"<
   >"Happy Birthday D"v
v"ppaH";"lanidraC rae"<
>"y Birthday To You"@
```

Output, using the "original" faulty interpreter:

```
Executing program..

Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear Cardinal
Happy Birthday To You

Execution complete.
>
```

You can test the program if you save it as txt file and drag it onto the interpreter exe for Windows.

http://esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal

Here is the interpreter:
http://floatation.webs.com/Cardinal.zip

Answer (score 2):

### CMD - 84 Bytes

```
cmd/v/c"set 1=to You&set 2=Dear CMD&for %a in (1,1,2,1)do @echo Happy Birthday !%a!"
```

Answer (score 2):

## jq: <s>54</s> 52 characters

(49 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```
0,0,1,0|"Happy Birthday "+["to You","Dear jq"][.]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n -r '0,0,1,0|"Happy Birthday "+["to You","Dear jq"][.]'
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear jq
Happy Birthday to You
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=0,0,1,0|%22Happy%20Birthday%20%22%2B[%22to%20You%22,%22Dear%20jq%22][.]&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Crayon](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Crayon), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"4*q2Y15X"Dear¤Crayon"q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/crayon#@6/kkVhQUKnglFlUkpGSWKlQkq8QmV/KpWSiVWgUaWgaoeSSmlh0aIlzUWJlfp5S4f//AA)

#### Explanation

Crayon's output is built on a 2-dimensional "canvas", which makes it ideal for ASCII art challenges. Text is drawn with a "crayon", which is a sort of cursor that moves around the canvas. Here's how this program works:

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"                        Push this string to the stack.
 4*                      Repeat the string 4 times.
   q                     Draw the string at the crayon (at (0,0) by default).
    2Y15X                Move the crayon to the "to" in the third line.
         "Dear¤Crayon"q  Push this string and draw it at the crayon.
                         Implicit: Output canvas
```

The `¤` represents byte `\x1F`; Crayon does not distinguish between the two. By default, a space does not overwrite the character underneath, so `¤` exists as a sort of "overwriting space".

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
4OHappy Birthday to You<esc>k2bCDear Vim
```

*4 bytes saved thanks to @DJMcMayhem by using `O` instead of `i...\n` and `k2bC` instead of `kd2bC`*

This uses a completely different approach to the previous Vim answer and hence I posted it as a separate answer. Outputs a trailing newline, but can be removed at the cost of one extra byte by using `Jk` instead of `k`.

Since V is reverse compatible with V, you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2/i75FYUFCp4JRZVJKRklipUJKvEJlfKp1tlOTskppYpBCWmfv/PwA)

Take that CJam!

Comment: This is the shortest competing solution, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

## [;#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121921/make-a-interpreter), 11644 bytes

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#
```

Code generated by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122256/66833) brainfuck program

Comment: Sorry, not a programming language.

Comment: @Challenger5 it doesn't have to be. The challenge is tagged with kolmogorov-complexity

Answer (score 2):

## Minecraft, 120 bytes

```
tellraw @a {"text":"Happy Birthday to You\nHappy Birthday to You\nHappy Birthday Dear Minecraft\nHappy Birthday to You"}
```

Can be run by pasting into a command block and supplying power to it, or pasting into the chat with a slash at the start.

Answer (score 2):

## [IDL (Interactive Data Language)](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/ProductsandTechnology/Software/IDL.aspx) – 47

Late entry (my first time here), but this looks like 3rd place after CJam and J!

Using IDL's Implied Print feature (since version 8.3), typing this at the command prompt:

```
'Happy Birthday '+[(u='to You'),u,'Dear IDL',u]
```

… will print the desired result to the console:

```
IDL> 'Happy Birthday '+[(u='to You'),u,'Dear IDL',u]
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear IDL
Happy Birthday to You
```

It works by creating (and implicitly printing) a four-element array, with `'Happy Birthday '` appended to each  of the four desired endings, made more concise/cryptic by assigning a variable `u` the value `'to You'` in the first instance, and reusing it twice later!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 52 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday to You"k₆,"Dear Brachylog"g,?,?↺,?ẉᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X8kjsaCgUsEps6gkIyWxUqEkXyEyv1Qp@1FTm46SS2pikYITTLVSuo69jv2jtl069g93dT7cOuH/fwA)

-1 thanks to [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize).

Comment: You can do 52 bytes by replacing `Z` with `?` and removing the first `Z` that unifies with the string.

Comment: @Fatalize Oh right the string unifies with `?`.

Answer (score 2):

## Unary, 2.715E2345 bytes

A string of zeroes with a length of `271544303753521374345784023617462447448766796991634195623271771343788064494033932467809637777433783261069835136468316635541569006957484008922172956907493623220358279584621153727394685316177875072717611870164011317998138133192412590581118711745080372132354520144049887264020357596958970682508119612069072184789433001139110110044141818883356102010044766108874743534376722033752443907309500308124800880956659496453762860029730933467190897780852535562502370486347488149358821225254933647032473098015846900520720300239993510123716590092279978630211422199772105659685365124211730629429856761187973769267382198582572968422104301126603859498501185917608874757741610893482041977003001381483481251619529628722427408338582339527157335234122942381275923949390605570564504822082772136057434464671123507495503027121245882553216512907124492451345153924551954324886539679044057026572440371334484657248811556813671966134409423451672608237773610848374597757496223902091127753821502096156978576733667670645804932685651998882744625271805968408192138003017383834286411465787825657955474390895833048578431020834761999769245058175985114327604667460675218915598066545717356728963407131382225834981689192053204022543453105950548359569307644293248265610511261123308873236361708287888512920927207140733264710153499926338085521461180344119631268486929440101264937117199882754841067458895376078972797675755102211602033168204711199744629239139853151734765325982327999734282103666604630769384354544377780974557091020653916122475973344426958326542939871981389127350485205414017350058299535652163085166091203298279054857159449355550278205308529995426116266317622349698148579685752377806473014344962213328458584663395562552762790574493037199848761427965675120816268240569132735553272845975553355819867289784427736974879735152861965319683108949477353673024614920892135291073944764379263817004591234093204928220689300382675729272978243082941205866127086587758323575891345926945843642967213885479373059430434109978135813970824413339027287055293233734939242557385167820253321966087885920624040254325137166864535273452145628538868866835395916784107310616214635120965693431403440614294637759561044455445706647271846433473546725069631283599186867863795122114084809385455487348989575611753135663244291563170055464760084089978670081473032469603515349502029160880861825869931824089974215244`

Comment: I thought this was a good score till I saw the "E"

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 57+1 for `-l` flag = 58 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday "ddd"to you"ddQJpnQJpn"Dear Aceto"QJpnsJp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//1/JI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVJBKSUlRakkX6EyvxTIDPQqyANhJZfUxCIFR5AWJRC/2Kvg//9/@QUlmfl5xf91cwA)

```
"Happy Birthday "                           push that string
                 ddd                        duplicate three times
                    "to you"                   push that string
                            dd                    duplicate twice
                              Q                    Pull from bottom of stack
                               Jpn                 Join, print, & newline
                                  QJpn               pull from bottom, &Join,print&\n
                                      "Dear Aceto"        push that string
                                                  QJpn      Pull,Join,print,\n
                                                      sJp     swap, Join, and print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ï■σ∞úφ♂mê▌δ↓T┌C▒7w↓√éº┌│╦╫C∩█ï
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8bfee5eca3ed0b6d88ddeb1954da43b1377719fb82a7dab3cbd743efdb8b&a=1)

### Explanation

Uses ASCII representation to explain:

```
`=%5#`GG`!0 ZrO"`GdG}`I#aq5J^oD}(`pQ

                    }                   Define a subroutine after the bracket
                     `I#aq5J^oD}(`      Push "Happy Birthday "
                                  p     Pop the string and print without newline
                                   Q    Peek the stack and print with newline

`=%5#`                                  Push "to You"
      GG                                Call the subroutine twice
        `!0 ZrO"`                       Push "Dear Stax"
                 G                      Call the subroutine
                  d                     Pop and discard "Dear Stax"
                   G                    Call the subroutine again
```

Comment: I like your favorite language.  Here's [28](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d4c5a0059e710aead4f2af47b13588eeca88c5d03b33107e99d615ba&i=&a=1) for the lead.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 56 bytes

```r
cat("",u<-"to You
",u,"Dear R
",u,sep="Happy Birthday ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qv7JFYUFCp4JRZVJKRklipUJKvEJlfykWksEtqYpFCEC7VXP@TE0s0lJR0Sm10laBiQI6OElQbiF2cWmCrhKZdSfP/fwA)

The old `sep=` trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 377 bytes

```
--->-->->>>>>->->>>>>>>>->-->>>->>>>-->->>>>->>>>>>>>>>+[-[>+++++++<-]<+++]>---->+>++>->+>+>++>--->++>>+>++>>->->++>--->->++>+>--->-->+>++>->++>>->+>--->->+>->>+>>++>->>++++[----[>+++++++<-]<++++]>---->--->+++>>+>+>+++>-->--->+>+++>-->>+++>>+++>-->+>-->>-->->>->+>->--->>+++>-->+>+++>>+>->-->->++>+++>--[++<++++]>>[.>]>[.>]<<[<<]>[.>]>[.>]<<[<<]>[.>]>[>]>[.>]<[[<]<]>>[.>]>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9BCgMxCHxQsC8QPyIetoVCWeihsO/PqqNpWagEHccxk9w/2@v9PB77nEQkcSSiKyBliVT8GooMJZWBYDL2Yq5z5XBasiQIZgiavL/IBAW/S6lZgjCMXQAPDYerbxvDCl4JmuumpmjA4GewopasnaLrrTlRt4Wn6E0sE7My25@@OVU2/t2a8wQ)

Most of the code sets up `"\nHappy Birthday \0to You\0Dear brainfuck"`. The last 64 instructions print it.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [aplay](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay), <s>360</s>, <s>175</s>, <s>167</s>, 151 bytes

Generates the contents of a WAV file onto `stdout`, singing the melody of Happy Birthday. The output can then be piped to, for example, `aplay` to listen to it.

Including `-lm` causes a +4 to score.

Also, thanks to ceilingcat for golfing a couple dozen bytes.

```c
c,i;main(t,T){for(;i<25;i++)for(t=T="$$(((0$$(((0$$((((($$(((0"[i]-32<<9;t--;)putchar(c=sin(exp("!!#!&%!!#!(&!!-*&%#++*&(&"[i]/17.-2)*t)*9*t/T+9);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzRCoIwFEC/ZVPH3ebNWkSM6V/4Fj3IJW2gJbooiH69lfTSy4HzcA5hRxQj5d4Njb9AyGv5bK8TOF@anfNay8VCVVc8TQFg/UeAn/CDP@LWlKV1AdHJ8Rbo3ExA1fxdnh4jcMYSJrKFIBhDJbJEayVALG2x2a/QSBWksioUtbbSvWJ8U9s33RzxHrEfPg) (won't produce sound, duh...)

Now [available on Clyp](https://clyp.it/pxekowbr) for listening. Amplified for convenience, may be *loud* and/or pop on some devices.

#### Try it offline!

Compile and listen with `gcc -w src.c -lm && ./a.out | aplay`

#### Degolf

```c
c,i;
main(t,T) {
    for(;i<25;i++) // 25 notes of the song in the loop, 25 notes of the song
        for(t=T="$$(((0$$(((0$$((((($$(((0"[i]-32<<9; // Select number of samples
                t--;)
            // See below, this has been mutilated quite a bit to golf it.
            // Assign to c for implicit cast to int.
            // A small shortcut is made by only dampening the sine-part of the wave.
            putchar(c=sin(exp("!!#!&%!!#!(&!!-*&%#++*&(&"[i]/17.-2)*t)*9*t/T+9);
}
```

A sine wave is defined as \$s(t)=A\cdot\sin 2\pi t\$. A sine wave with frequency \$f\$ can thus be expressed as \$s(ft)\$. Now, in this case \$\{t\in\mathbb N \mid0\leq t \leq T \}\$ and \$T:=n\cdot2^{11}\$, so we have to divide \$t\$ with 2048, in order to make the signal function work. Our function is now \$s(2^{-11}\cdot ft)\$.

Since listing the frequencies would take a significant amount of bytes, I have encoded the frequencies as halfsteps relative to A4, represented by 40 or `(` in the string. The frequency is thus obtained \$f=440Hz \cdot 2^{c-40\over12}\$. Finally, putting it all together, adding in some dampening and ensuring outputs greater than zero, we get:

$$ f(t)= \Bigg({T - t\over T}\Bigg) \Bigg({A\over2}+{A\over2}\sin \Big({880 \pi t \cdot 2^{c-40\over12}\cdot2^{-11}} \Big)\Bigg) $$

$$ f(t)= \Bigg({T - t\over T}\Bigg) \Bigg({A\over2}+{A\over2}\sin \Big({880 \pi t \cdot \exp\Big({{c\ln 2-40\ln 2\over12} - 11 \ln 2}}\Big) \Big)\Bigg) $$

$$ f(t)= \Bigg({T - t\over T}\Bigg) \Bigg({A\over2}+{A\over2}\sin \Big({ t \cdot \exp\Big({{c\ln 2-40\ln 2\over12} - 11 \ln 2 + \ln 880 \pi}}\Big) \Big)\Bigg) $$

$$ f(t)\approx \Bigg({T - t\over T}\Bigg) \Bigg({A\over2}+{A\over2}\sin \Big({t \cdot \exp \Big({c\over17}-2\Big)} \Big)\Bigg) $$

And finally, we select \${A\over2}=9\$ to conserve bytes.

Comment: Mad and brilliant! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language (IPEL)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 96 or 60 bytes

I call this language both "International Phonetic Esoteric Language" and "IPEL". So, 2 answers:

```
"Happy Birthday ""to You"dbudbodbudbodbud"Dear International Phonetic Esoteric Language"odbudbod
```

```
"Happy Birthday ""to You"dbudbodbudbodbud"Dear IPEL"odbudbod
```

### Explanation

```
"Happy Birthday ""to You"dbudbodbudbodbud"Dear IPEL"odbudbod
"Happy Birthday ""to You"                                    (push strings)
                         dbudbodbudbo                        (print "Happy Birthday to You" twice)
                                     dbud"Dear IPEL"o        (print "Happy Birthday to [lang]")
                                                     dbudbod (one more "Happy Birthday to You")
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;++i<5;)console.log(`Happy Birthday ${i==3?'Dear JavaScript':'to You'}`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PWwFpbO9PG1FozOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jwSOxoKBSwSmzqCQjJbFSQaU609bW2F7dJTWxSMELaFAw2CB1K/WSfIXI/FL12gTN//8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 30 bytes

```
`†‟ ¨ǎ to λ•`D:⌈2ẎṄ` βṄ ₴ŀ`+$W
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%60%E2%80%A0%E2%80%9F%20%C2%A8%C7%8E%20to%20%CE%BB%E2%80%A2%60D%3A%E2%8C%882%E1%BA%8E%E1%B9%84%60%20%CE%B2%E1%B9%84%20%E2%82%B4%C5%80%60%2B%24W&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 66 bytes

> *I was determined to beat Dave Neeley's answer of 71 bytes*

```powershell
$h="Happy Birthday";($b="$h to You`r")*2;"$h Dear PowerShell`r";$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXDVskjsaCgUsEps6gkIyWxUslaQyXJVkklQ6EkXyEyvzShSElTy8gaJOCSmlikEADSHQzSDZSxVkn6/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP - <strike>87</strike> <strike>80</strike> 78 chars**

```
<? $h="<br>Happy birthday ";$t="to you";$d="dear PHP";echo "$h$t$h$t$h$d$h$t";
```

I don't think that PHP is a good language for golfing, but I'm still practicing. And I love PHP :)

For the command line (strip off the short tags and replace the `<br>` with `\n`) **73 chars**:

```
$h="\nHappy birthday ";$t="to you";$d="dear PHP";echo "$h$t$h$t$h$d$h$t";
```

Comment: I think you can skip the `<? ?>` because you can run it with `-r` on the command line.

Comment: Even on a webpage, you don't need the closing `?>`, two more chars saved.

Comment: @OlivierTheOlive Thanks. My PHP is a little rusty, I've not used it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell 79

```
$a = 'Happy Birthday '
$b = 'to You'
"$a$b`n$a$b`n$($a)Dear PowerShell`n$a$b"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Railo CFML (79 characters)

```
for(i=1;i<5;i++){writeoutput("<br>Happy Birthday "&(i<>3?"to you":"dear CF"));}
```

### Just having some fun creating a ridiculous mess:

```
  variables.endings = ["H,a,p,p,y, ,B,i,r,t,h,d,a,y, ,t,o, ,y,o,u","H,a,p,p,y, ,B,i,r,t,h,d,a,y, ,t,o, ,y,o,u","H,a,p,p,y, ,B,i,r,t,h,d,a,y, ,d,e,a,r, ,C,o,l,d, ,F,u,s,i,o,n,n,n,n,n","H,a,p,p,y, ,B,i,r,t,h,d,a,y, ,t,o, ,y,o,u"];
  variables.iVerse = '';
  for (i = 1; i <= ArrayLen(variables.endings); i++) {
    variables.iLine = '';
    for (i2 = 1; i2 <= ListLen(variables.endings[i]); i2++) {
      iLine = iLine & ListGetAt(variables.endings[i],i2);
    }
    variables.iVerse = variables.iVerse & variables.iLine;
    if (i < ArrayLen(variables.endings)) {
      variables.iVerse = variables.iVerse & "<br />";
    }
  }

  writeOutput(variables.iVerse);
```

Comment: I know it's a little obvious what language this is, but please, describe what language you used and the character count of your code. Also, try to shorten it as much as you can.

Comment: @g.carvalho97 I was having too much fun, sorry. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure : 87 chars

Golfed:

```
(let[h"Happy Birthday "s(str h"to You\n")t(str h"Dear Clojure\n")](print(str s s t s)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(let [ h "Happy Birthday "
       s (str h "to You\n")
       t (str h "Dear Clojure\n") ]
(print (str s s t s)))
```

Comment: Or `81` with the similar `(let[h"Happy Birthday "s"to You\n"t"Dear Clojure\n"](map #(print h %)[s s t s]))`

Answer (score 1):

## C: 87

```c
#define p(a)printf("Happy birthday %s\n",a?a:"to you");
main(){p(0)p(0)p("dear C")p(0)}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/F8cRonCO)

Compiles fine, but since it doesn't return, it might not exit correctly. If you want it to return 0, it'll cost another seven characters:

```c
#define p(a)printf("Happy birthday %s\n",a?a:"to you");
main(){p(0)p(0)p("dear C")return!p(0)}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/vm0y9rCJ)

Answer (score 1):

## Common LISP, 169 bytes

```
(defun birthday ()
   (princ "Happy Birthday to You")
   (princ "Happy Birthday to You")
   (princ "Happy Birthday dear Common LISP")
   (princ "Happy Birthday to You"))
```

**Output:**

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday dear Common LISP
Happy Birthday to You
```

Comment: This is a [tag:code-golf] challenge but this isn't really golfed...

Answer (score 1):

## Burlesque - 55 Characters

```
"Happy Birthday to You"4.*g_15.+"Dear Burlesque".+2iauN
```

[Test it here.](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=%22Happy+Birthday+to+You%224.*g_15.%2B%22Dear+Burlesque%22.%2B2iauN)

Comment: `"Happy Birthday " "to You"4.*"Dear Burlesque"3ia?+uN` would be a shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 85**

```
[print('Happy Birthday %s'%('dear Python' if x==2 else 'to you')) for x in range(4)]
```

Comment: The `if`/`else` idiom can be generally shortened to a list selection: `['to you','dear Python'][x==2]`. Instead of string formatting `%`, you can just use string concatenation. Take a look at some Python golf tips: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 78

```cobra
class P
    def main
        print (t=(l='Happy Birthday ')+'to You\n')+t+l+'Dear Cobra\n'+t
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 61

Based on @Falko's answer I made one for Python 3.3. I slightly improved his code by removing the space at the beginning of "Dear Python" and using the space between 'Birthday' and 'to'.

```
H="\nHappy Birthday to You"
print((H*3)[:60]+"Dear Python"+H)
```

Total number of characters is <strike>60</strike> 61.(thanks for the recount @manatwork)

#### Edit:

Two slightly different approaches, all with the same number of characters:

```
T="\nHappy Birthday to You"
print(T*2+T[:-6]+"Dear Python"+T)
```

or

```
print(T*2+T[:16]+"Dear Python"+T)
```

BTW: I would like to post this as a comment, but I do not have the rep.

Comment: Sure about the 60 characters? Seems 61 to me.

Comment: @manatwork: you are right. Somehow my character counter gave the wrong output. It is also logic that I loss one character compared with Falko, because I need two parentheses and win one character by changing the "Dear Python" phrase.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge: 103

```
 >"yadhtriB yppaH"67+>:#,_1g:"0"-v
2^_@#-"0"g20p10-1,,,,,,," to You"_1+01p"egnufeB raeD ">:#,_"0"02p#
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## J Script(63)

```
alert((a=(x="\nHappy Birthday ")+"to You")+a+x+"Dear JScript"+a)
```

Why [J Script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) and not Java Script? -3 bytes:)

Comment: I don't see why this has been downvoted...

Comment: @BetaDecay coz JS is not the language name.

Comment: @Optimizer Ah, I see now...

Comment: @Optimizer now it is the language name.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 90

[Try it out here](http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground) or [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_befunge_online.php)

```
4v>$"uoY ot"     v
v>0" yadhtriB yppaH" >:#,_$
< |-2\+49\0:
 v>"egnufeB raeD">:#,_$1-:!#@_
```

Comment: If I recollect correctly `\r` is the Mac OS linebreak; `\r\n` is the Windows linebreak; and `\n` is the *nix linebreak.

Comment: Oops, yes I meant Mac (prior to OS X anyway). Apparently any of these line breaks should work according to the [Funge-98 specs](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#funge-source-file-format). I just checked the interpreter at compileonline.com and it seems happy to accept `\r` so I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

### C# (83)

```
using System;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)Console.WriteLine("Happy Birthday "+(i!=2?"to You":"Dear C#"));

//Happy Birthday To You
//Happy Birthday To You
//Happy Birthday Dear C#
//Happy Birthday To You
```

Equally short (83 Bytes of code) is:

```
int i=0;while(i<4)Console.WriteLine("Happy Birthday "+(i++!=2?"to You":"Dear C#"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bc: 62 characters

(This demonstrates the language's only golfing strength: string literals are displayed even without the `print` statement.)

```
while(i++<4){"Happy Birthday "
if(i-3)"To You
"else"Dear bc
"}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bc <<< 'while(i++<4){"Happy Birthday "
> if(i-3)"To You
> "else"Dear bc
> "}'
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear bc
Happy Birthday To You
```

Answer (score 1):

### J : 53 bytes

```
'Dear J'(57+i.6)"_}'to You',"1~,~,:~'Happy Birthday '
```

`,"1~,~,:~` and `(57+i.6)"_` can probably be golfed further.

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal (83) in maXbox

```
  const H='Happy Birthday to You';
  Speak(H+H+DelString(H,'to You')+'Dear Pascal'+H);
```

See more: https://github.com/maxkleiner/maXbox3/releases

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure -- 79

```
(map #(println"Happy Birthday"%)(assoc(vec(repeat 4"to You"))2"Dear Clojure"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure (<del>104</del> 76 characters)

```
(let[h "Happy Birthday" t "to You\n"](print h t h t h "Dear Clojure\n" h t))
```

which prints

```
Happy Birthday to You
 Happy Birthday to You
 Happy Birthday Dear Clojure
 Happy Birthday to You
```

Answer (score 1):

## Falcon: 61

```
for i in[:4]:>"Happy Birthday "+(i==2?"Dear Falcon":"to You")
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript (75)

```
h="Happy Birthday "
l=vbLF
t="to You"&l
x=h&t
WScript.Echo x&x&h&"Dear VBS"&l&x
```

69 bytes if replacing `WScript.Echo` with `MsgBox` would be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**Rexx: 87**

```
p='a'x;h='Happy Birthday';i='to you';ooray='dear Rexx'p;!=h i;say h i p   h i p   h ooray !
```

Output:

```
Happy Birthday to you 
 Happy Birthday to you 
 Happy Birthday dear Rexx
 Happy Birthday to you
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# (Full program) - 162

```
namespace O{class P{static void Main(string[] a){for(int i=0;i<4;)System.Console.Write("Happy Birthday {0}\n",++i==3?"Dear god why do I golf in C#?":"to you");}}}
```

Comment: "Dear god why do I golf in C#?" -- Try vba, it's worse.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript,  82**

Yet another different js entry

```
a='Happy Birthday %s';b='to You\n';console.log(a+a+a+a,b,b,'Dear Javascript\n',b)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi - <strike>124</strike> <strike>122</strike> 115

Another Delphi XE2 try, this time without a loop.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}const l=#13#10;y='to you'+l;h='Happy birthday ';d='dear Delphi'+l;begin
Write(h+y+h+y+h+d+h+y)end.
```

Comment: `Write` is enough there as the "_Ln_" part you output literally.

Comment: And again you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

## Rant, <s>58</s> 54 chars

```
[r:4]{Happy Birthday [alt:[nth:3;Dear Rant];to You]\N}
```

[Online Version](http://berkin.me/rantbox#0F7EC43E16FE98E2CC3B91C09E9850AE271E5284)

**How it Works:**

- `[r:4]` - Sets repetitions of next block to 4.
- `[alt: ... ; ...]` - Executes alternate code if a primary pattern prints nothing.

  - `[nth:3;Dear Rant]` - Prints "Dear Rant" on the third iteration.
  - If the `nth` condition is not satisfied, the `alt` function prints `to You`.

Answer (score 1):

**Intersystems Cache M, *(71)***

```
S X="Happy Birthday "
S Y="to You"
S Z="Dear M"
W X,Y,!,X,Y,!,X,Z,!,X,Y
```

Sample run...

```
USER>S X="Happy Birthday "

USER>S Y="to You"

USER>S Z="Dear M"

USER>W X,Y,!,X,Y,!,X,Z,!,X,Y
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear M
Happy Birthday to You
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 107

Nice:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){[](){}();//<-Good Luck Charm
    for (auto b : {false, false, true, false})
        std::cout << "Happy Birthday " << (b ? "Dear C++" : "To You") << '\n';
}
```

Golfed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){for(int b:"\0\0?")std::cout<<"Happy Birthday "<<(b?"Dear C++":"To You")<<'\n';}
```

Comment: How should I compile this? `gcc` without any switch says: “nwp.cpp:2:22: error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode”.

Comment: @manatwork `-std=c++11` should do the trick.

Comment: Nope. :( http://pastebin.com/eZUpZXve BTW, its `gcc` 4.8.2 on Linux. As neither the ungolfed version compiles, I suppose on my side is broken something…

Comment: @manatwork Looks like gcc does not find the standard library. I don't know how exactly to fix that. You can semi-run the code at [ideone](http://ideone.com/WXcUdv).

Comment: @manatwork Now I remember. Ignore the standard library comment. Instead of `gcc` use `g++` to compile.

Comment: Works! Thanks. I always suspected my C++ is insufficient, but now I got the proof. :S

Answer (score 1):

## sh - 59

```
echo "${h=Happy Birthday }${y=to You}
$h$y
${h}Dear sh
$h$y
```

I thought this solution would be worth sharing too, even though there's a shorter one.

Answer (score 1):

## K, 45 bytes

No one has sung Happy Birthday for everyone's favorite in-memory columnar database language? There, there:

```
`0:4 21#(57#"Happy Birthday to You"),"Dear K"
```

Very similar to the APL approach by @Moris Zucca- repeat the string `Happy Birthday to You` slightly more than two times and then glue on the `Dear K`. Reshaping into a 4x21 matrix repeats the initial line. In K, sending text to stdout requires the `0:` IO verb. Without it (for 3 fewer characters), we would print:

```
  4 21#(57#"Happy Birthday to You"),"Dear K"
("Happy Birthday to You"
 "Happy Birthday to You"
 "Happy Birthday Dear K"
 "Happy Birthday to You")
```

An alternate 47 character solution I considered was:

```
`0:("Happy Birthday ",("to You";"Dear K")2=)'!4
```

This is about as straightforward as it gets- map a function over the sequence `0 1 2 3` given by `!4`, select the second half of the verse based on whether this index is equal to 2, glue on the start of the verse and then print the whole list out.

Comment: There's no in-memory columnar database language I like better.

Answer (score 1):

## JMP/JSL, 67

Like the Mathematica example by David Carraher, this will 'sing' (...read) the Happy Birthday message to you out loud.

```
speak(x="\!nHappy Birthday";y=x||" to You";y||y||x||" Dear JSL"||y)
```

Output:

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday Dear JSL
Happy Birthday to You
```

For 7 less bytes you will have the Happy Birthday message printed for you in the log

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 66 bytes

```
data;a='Happy Birthday';b=a||' to You';put b/b/a 'Dear SAS'/b;run;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua - 72 bytes

Straightforward, but none of the other Lua programs work this way.

```lua
a,b,c='Happy Birthday ','to You\n','Dear Lua\n'io.write(a,b,a,b,a,c,a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 157

```
v
\0&
v                                   <
\&:&2(?v
       >"Happy Birthday to you"a&1+&^
\"Happy Birthday dear ><>"a\
v  a"uoy ot yadhtriB yppaH"/
r
>l?!;o
```

Big, but I wanted it to be different from the Befunge answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [G*](https://github.com/m654z/g-asterisk), 76 bytes

G* is a golfing language I made but it seems it failed miserably :P (Note that this isn't even close to my favorite language but I wanted to give it a try at code golf.)

```
l 2 p Happy birthday to you;p Happy birthday dear G*;p Happy birthday to you
```

Here's another (longer) one:

```
1=Happy birthday to you;@ 1;@ 1;p Happy birthday dear G*;p Happy birthday to you
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 91 bytes

```
var s="Happy Birthday to You\n";System.Console.Write(s+s+s.Substring(0, 15)+"Dear C#\n"+s);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), 66 chars

I created beeswax in December 2015. This solution is just for fun.

```
>`y Dear beeswax`5Np
pb"M`adhtriB yppaH`<3~4_
>`y To You`N~L;~   d
```

You can clone the beeswax interpreter, language specifications and instructions from [my GitHub repository](https://www.github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl).

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way 1.6.5](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 56 bytes

```
I"Happy Birthday ":"Dear Milky Way"+;"to You"+::>>J§{!}
```

---

#### Explanation

```
I                                                        ` empty the stack
 "Happy Birthday "                                       ` push the string
                  :"Dear Milky Way"+                     ` make the 3rd line
                                    ;"to You"+::         ` make the 1st, 2nd and 4th lines
                                                >>       ` put the lines in order
                                                  J§{!}  ` print each line
```

---

#### Usage

```
$ ./mw <path-to-code>
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 76 bytes

```
for i=0 to 3 do printfn"Happy Birthday %s"<|if i=2 then"Dear F#"else"to You"
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Golisp](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/golisp), <s>102</s> 100 bytes

EDIT: Removed 2 bytes by changing the last `writeln` to `write`

```
write@*["Happy Birthday to You\n"2]writeln@"Happy Birthday Dear Golisp"write@"Happy Birthday to You"
```

Ungolfed & commented version:

```
write @ *["Happy Birthday to You\n" 2] # Call write with "Happy Birthday to You\n" repeated 2 times (f@x == f[x]) #
writeln @ "Happy Birthday Dear Golisp" # Write "Happy Birthday Dear Golisp" to stdout #
write @ "Happy Birthday to You" # Write "Happy Birthday to You" to stdout #
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ñƒẉ%VİỊ½żƒ»µ,;“©ʋ⁶ẓsŀKɗʠØ»,⁸¤Y
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=4oCcw5HGkuG6iSVWxLDhu4rCvcW8xpLCu8K1LDvigJzCqcqL4oG24bqTc8WAS8mXyqDDmMK7LOKBuMKkWQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 44 bytes

Pushy doesn't actually have a string type. However, it has the command `"`, which interprets the current stack as a character list and prints it.

```
`Happy Birthday `V`to You`""F`dear Pushy`"F"
```

It's quite simple:

```
`Happy Birthday `      % Push chars
V                      % Copy into stack 2
`to You`               % Push chars
""                     % Print stack 1 twice ("Happy Birthday to You")
F                      % Go to stack 2
`dear Pushy`           % Push chars
"                      % Print stack ("Happy Birthday dear Pushy")
F"                     % Print other stack again to complete the song.
```

Basically, it uses the two stacks to construct the two needed strings, and prints them as it goes along. Here's the output:

```
$ pushy happybday.pshy

Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday dear Pushy
Happy Birthday to You
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>68</s> 65 bytes

There are already 4 PHP answers, most of them shorter than this, but none using this feature, so:

```php
for(;$i++<4;)echo"
Happy Birthday ",["to You","Dear PHP"][$i==3];
```

<sub>Am I the only one noticing that there´s a comma missing?</sub>

Comment: Am I the only one noticing that there's a useless `?:0`?

Answer (score 1):

## ZPL ([Zebra Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(programming_language))), 112 bytes

This is a just for fun answer.

```
^XA^FB137,4^FDHappy Birthday to You\&Happy Birthday to You\&Happy Birthday Dear ZPL\&Happy Birthday to You^FS^XZ
```

**[Try It Online](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=6&width=1&height=1&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%5EFB137%2C4%5EFDHappy%20Birthday%20to%20You%5C%26Happy%20Birthday%20to%20You%5C%26Happy%20Birthday%20Dear%20ZPL%5C%26Happy%20Birthday%20to%20You%5EFS%5EXZ)**

**Explanation:**

```
^XA                                # Start Format
    ^FB                            # Field Block
        137,                       # Width of text block line (in dots)
        4                          # Maximum number of lines in text block
    ^FD                            # Field Data
        Happy Birthday to You      # Hardcoded String
        \&                         # New Line (as allowed by the ^FB command)
        Happy Birthday to You      # Hardcoded String
        \&                         # New Line (as allowed by the ^FB command)
        Happy Birthday Dear ZPL    # Hardcoded String
        \&                         # New Line (as allowed by the ^FB command)
        Happy Birthday to You      # Hardcoded String
    ^FS                            # Field Separator
^XZ                                # End Format
```

**Note:** *The Zebra Programming Language is a printer control language that is not Turing complete.*

Answer (score 1):

### COBOL, 185 Bytes

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. H.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
PERFORM X.
PERFORM X.
DISPLAY 'Happy Birthday Dear COBOL'.
PERFORM X.
STOP RUN.
X.
DISPLAY 'Happy Birthday to You'.
STOP RUN.
```

I'm sure there is a shorter way but I don't know COBOL that well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, <s>69 68</s> 65

```
puts "[set t [set h Happy\ Birthday]\ To\ You]
$t
$h Dear tcl
$t"
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/MZSQK96239)

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 58 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and makes VBA sing its own happy birthday song, alone.

```vba
h="Happy Birthday ":t="to You":?h;t:?h;t:?h"Dear VBA":?h;t
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 78 bytes

```sql
SELECT a+b+a+b+a+c+a+b
FROM(SELECT'Happy Birthday 'a,'to You
'b,'Dear SQL
'c)t
```

SQL strings can include line breaks. If you are using SSMS, make sure to use "Results to Text" instead of "Results to Grid"

I used a different technique than the two excellent SQL answers already here:

- [MickyT's answer using `STUFF...FROM VALUES`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39777/70172)
- [Kyle Hale's answer using `STUFF(REPLICATE(...))`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39840/70172)

If a *leading* newline is allowed (not mentioned in the rules or addressed in the comments), I can save one byte by moving the line break to the beginning of the 'Happy Birthday' string.:

```sql
SELECT a+b+a+b+a+c+a+b
FROM(SELECT'
Happy Birthday 'a,'to You'b,'Dear SQL'c)t
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>70</strike> 64 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(;++x<5;)print"Happy Birthday",x~3?"Dear AWK":"to You"}
```

Thanks for the suggestion @PedroMaimere :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9Iw1pbu8LG1FqzoCgzr0TJI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVJJp6LO2F7JJTWxSMEx3FvJSqkkXyEyv1Sp9v9/AA)

Comment: Taking advantage of parsing and omitting spaces: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9Iw1pbu8LG1FqzoCgzr0TJI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVJJp6LO2F7JJTWxSMEx3FvJSqkkXyEyv1Sp9v9/AA "AWK – Try It Online") `BEGIN{for(;++x<5;)print"Happy Birthday",x~3?"Dear AWK":"to You"}`

Comment: Could also do: `BEGIN{for(;++x<5;)print"Happy Birthday",x-3?"to You":"Dear AWK"}`

Guess I need to look up the '~' operator :)

Comment: be careful, though. With more than one digit, it does not behave as `==` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxAcAgCEXB/s3hAHwwKuNYZwA7Vye59vZ5q5pdVQkn6DwMJotEhoQSN/zvJIzQBw "AWK – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

**REXX: 73 bytes**

```
n='Happy Birthday to You'   
m='Happy Birthday Dear REXX'
say n                       
say n                       
say m                       
say n
```

**SAY** echoes the data and the output is

```
Happy Birthday to You   
Happy Birthday to You   
Happy Birthday Dear REXX
Happy Birthday to You
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 74 bytes *i know it's too much*

```
b="Happy Birthday to You\n"
print(b+b+b.replace("to You","Dear Python")+b)
```

[So like... I made the string, and then printed it, tore some off, added some more, and printed it. There ya go.](https://repl.it/@How_ToTo1/WingedAppropriateType)

Comment: It may be longer than the [current shortest Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39757/52210), but it's a to-the-point approach and a nice first answer nonetheless. +1 from me. Welcome to PPCG, and enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: Thanks! I think code golf is a lot of fun. It's just hard for me to think in code sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 373 bytes

```
[N
S T S 
N_Call_Label_to_You\n][N
S T 
N_Call_Label_Happy_Birthday_][S S T T   S T T   T   S S N
_Push_-92_newline][S S T    T   N
_Push_-1_e][S S T   T   T   N
_Push_-3_c][S S T   T   S T N
_Push_-5_a][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10_p][S S S T T   S T N
_Push_13_s][S S T   T   N
_Push_-1_e][S S S T T   T   S N
_Push_14_t][S S S T T   N
_Push_3_i][S S S T  S N
_Push_2_h][S S T    T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-15_W][S S T  T   S S S T T   S N
_Push_-70_space][S S S T    T   S S N
_Push_12_r][S S T   T   S T N
_Push_-5_a][S S T   T   N
_Push_-1_e][S S T   T   S S S T S N
_Push_-34_D][N
S T 
N_Call_Label_Happy_Birthday_][N
S T S 
N_Call_Label_to_You\n][N
S T 
N_Call_Label_Happy_Birthday_][N
S T S 
N_Call_Label_to_You\n][N
S T 
N_Call_Label_Happy_Birthday_][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T T   S S T   T   S N
_Push_102][T    S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S N
_Create_Label_Happy_Birthday_][S S T    T   S S S T T   S N
_Push_-70_space][S S S T    S S T   T   N
_Push_19_y][S S T   T   S T N
_Push_-5_a][S S T   T   S N
_Push_-2_d][S S S T S N
_Push_2_h][S S S T  T   T   S N
_Push_14_t][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_r][S S S T T   N
_Push_3_i][S S T    T   S S T   S S N
_Push_-36_B][S S T  T   S S S T T   S N
_Push_-70_space][S S S T    S S T   T   N
_Push_19_y][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10_p][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S S T T   S T N
_Push_-5_a][S S T   T   T   T   T   S N
_Push_-30_H][N
T   N
_Return][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_to_You\n][S S T   T   S T T   T   S S N
_Push_-92_newline][S S S T  T   T   T   N
_Push_15_u][S S S T S S T   N
_Push_9_o][S S T    T   T   S T N
_Push_-13_Y][S S T  T   S S S T T   S N
_Push_-70_space][S T    S S T   S N
_Copy_2nd_o][S S S T    T   T   S N
_Push_14_t][N
T   N
_Return]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVBbCoBACPzWU8zVIoL6Cwo6vtnothkFi7o6Mz6OedmnbR3GyUwhUDcKiPgTgCFNy7pzmIBeEhyflgxIsBqPJjnQSo1ytNaPIJtKaBCsl4iy@NbvounucR4joo9K3V@Z3LVsS5lojnor5MKkBxb1AFJmcRGzEw).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Call function to_You\n
Call function Happy_Birthday_
Push values for "\necapsetihW raeD" (reversed of "Dear Whitespace\n") to the stack
Call function Happy_Birthday_
Call function to_You\n
Call function Happy_Birthday_
Call function to_You\n
Call function Happy_Birthday_
Start LOOP:
  Integer i = top value of the stack
  i = i + 102
  Print i as character to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function Happy_Birthday_:
  Push values for " yadhtriB yppaH" (reversed of "Happy Birthday ") to the stack
  Return

function to_You\n:
  Push values for "\nuoY ot" (reversed of "to You\n") to the stack
  Return
```

Constant 102 was generated with [this Java program](https://tio.run/##bVFba9swFH7PrzjoSUKpaWFhLI4oDS3MsPRhXnehLUV21ESZI7vSccGM/PZUjuNLuurBwue7nXO0ka/ybLP8u9@nmXQOFlKbfyOAokwynYJDif56zfUSth6iMVptVvePIFlNA2gKYJUrMwQB5Kssigrm2uJ6KSvAHP7k5YO5VtLCr7VG5QqZqgdDwoNeGwS3lVmmXC2PDKqVssHi6vfTz6tvdzdjiMTnSTjMaunfu8yj13Nuae2nRRTq2cXkPNScH/vsOxWEjHFciFbV6JIKFSTTZo5gpXDuC46yTg6AgsQx4TQ507PzS/KDTElMWNjhbXw6bafAfK6NtFUTTWuULSSuA5m42oaxj5N8Fhfp7NOXS58w9Ul9yG40oJDbbo/1sYJioF5KmTlaMK/1sNcj47YnFQLbn9ZLP1MbZMqscE0ZzLoFDzr6b@cDx8Hz9TY9HPm6Po1svnHlUG2DvMSg8PvBzFDSyAXhrSknoX9PwiNO/KxH2/dKetregbUb7fb7Nw), and used with [this Whitespace tip of mine to print the text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210) by putting the values reversed to the stack, and looping over them (adding the contant value, and printing them as character to the stack; which also exits as soon as we don't have any more values on the stack).

In addition, the functions with return are used to prevent duplicated code for the repeated parts of the output-text. And there were two more things to golf:

1. The value for the second `p` in `"Happy"` (which was `SSSTSTSN` - push 10) has been replaced with `SNS` (duplicate top).
2. The value for the second `o` in `"to You"` (which was `SSSTSSTN` - push 9) has been replaced with `STSSTSN` (copy 2nd [1-indexed]). ([Relevant Whitespace tip of mine.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158230/52210))

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
J." y-÷\n3ª¼öj"K+J"to you"KK+J"dear Pyth"K

J." y-÷\n3ª¼öj"                            Assign J to "Happy Birthday "
               K+J"To you"                 Assign K to J + "to you"
                          KK               Print K twice
                            +J"dear Pyth"  Print J+"dear Pyth"
                                         K Print K
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 29 bytes

```
”to€î”Ð”¬Ž 05AB1E”s)”ŽØ¢© ”ì»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPckvxHTWsOrwOyDk8AEofWHN2rYGDq6GToCuQVawKJo3sPzzi06NBKBZCaNYd2//8PAA)

```
”to€î”                 # dictionary string "to You"
      Ð                # triplicate
”¬Ž 05AB1E”            # dictionary string "Dear 05AB1E"
           s           # swap
            )          # wrap entire stack in an array
”ŽØ¢© ”                # dictionary string "Happy Birthday "
       ì               # prepend to each string in the array
        »              # join array by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fw6jGI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVKhJF8hMr80hkuTC03CJTWxSME7NT2GC6uO//8B), 74 bytes

```
(2|Happy Birthday to You\
)
Happy Birthday Dear Keg\
Happy Birthday to You
```

Comment: I feel like I may be seeing this again in 2 months!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▄Jÿø•2╜x!╨¬r├^↑#8╕Γ☺°7¿5⌠☻U▄
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=dc4a98000732bd7821d0aa72c35e182338b8e201f837a835f40255dc&i=&a=1)

I'm two weeks late. Alas. But it's short, at least...

#### Unpacked (34 bytes) and explanation:

```
`/&tpz/b}"=J:J=P*``!0 ZrO"`n)ncLmT

`/&tpz/b}"=J:J=P*`                    Literal "Happy Birthday to You   "
                  `!0 ZrO"`           Literal "Dear Stax"
                           n          Copy the first line to the top of the stack
                            )         Overwrite end with "Dear Stax"
                             nc       Copy the first line twice more to the top
                               L      Collect stack in a list
                                mT    Print each, trimmed of trailing spaces, on its own line
```

If you're fine with those three trailing spaces, drop the `T` for 33 bytes unpacked. Still 28 packed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `d`, 34 bytes

Short language name to the rescue!

W is just 0.0833 years old but I'm still posting this ... Insanely long but oh well.

```
♣∙♥ª¬^╗Γë├ΦñtQOi▼!◙╖☼▓Φ◙ï╔♀EÞr!R╫J
```

### Explanation

```
4                                       E % Foreach in the range from 1 to 4:
 "Happy Birthday "                        % Append the string "Happy Birthday "
                  a3=                     % If this is the third line:
                     "Dear W"&            % Output "Dear W"
                              "to You"|   % Otherwise, output "to You"
                                       +  % Join the two strings.
                                          % Output a newline.
```

Answer (score 1):

## **JavaScript (<s>84</s> 76 bytes)**

```js
x=`Happy Birthday To You\n`,alert(x+x+`Happy birthday Dear JavaScript\n`+x)
```

Output:

```
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear JavaScript
Happy Birthday To You
```

Comment: You have an extra “s” in “JavaScript”. And `x+x` is shorter than `x.repeat(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 46 bytes

```
/~/
Happy Birthday //-/~to You/--~Dear \/\/\/-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X79On8sjsaCgUsEps6gkIyWxUkFfX1e/riRfITK/VF9Xt84lNbFIIUYfBHX//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 63 bytes

```julia
a="Happy Birthday To You\n";print(a^2*a[1:15]*"Dear Julia\n"*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P9FWySOxoKBSwSmzqCQjJbFSISRfITK/NCZPybqgKDOvRCMxzkgrMdrQytA0VkvJJTWxSMELpBmoQCtR8/9/AA)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! I've edited your answer just a little bit to be closer to the standard answer format we use on the site, including a link to an online interpreter so others can test your code

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 210 bytes

```
1x1f0m9a8m1o9a9a7a1o9a6a2o9a1o4d2a1o2d4m2a1o5d8m1a1o9a1o2a1o9s3s1o4s1o3s1o9a9a6a1o4d2a1o0x1x2f2d7m4a1o5s1o3d5s1o3m7s1o3d4m5s1o6a1o9d3s1o0x1f2f1f2f1f2m4a1o3d5m9s1o4s1o9a8a1o3d6s1o3m9a5a1o9s4s1o9a9a7a1o9d3s1o1f2f
```

I haven't had much time for code golf lately, but I had to get this challenge knocked out: at the time of writing, [naz's GitHub repo was created exactly 1 year and a few minutes ago.](https://github.com/sporeball/naz/commit/b6fa2e98ce673ed1265c63d2a28e32c5969dc4e5) Happy birthday, my child.

Output includes an extra trailing newline.

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
# Function 1
# Output "Happy Birthday "
1x1f0m9a8m1o9a9a7a1o9a6a2o9a1o4d2a1o2d4m2a1o5d8m1a1o9a1o2a1o9s3s1o4s1o3s1o9a9a6a1o4d2a1o
# Function 2
# Output "to You\n"
1x2f2d7m4a1o5s1o3d5s1o3m7s1o3d4m5s1o6a1o9d3s1o

1f2f1f2f1f                                                 # Output the first 2.5 lines
2m4a1o3d5m9s1o4s1o9a8a1o3d6s1o3m9a5a1o9s4s1o9a9a7a1o9d3s1o # Output "Dear naz\n"
1f2f                                                       # Output the last line
```

Comment: happy birthday naz!

Answer (score 1):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), <s>433</s> 211 bytes

*-222 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

```
3∞н5Ćf–γúpïJ₂BΛ™H&¬¡ÌÿD"çÑ^oºvÄv»Ö{ž£&B#žà₆?àë”%₄J€Ba{‹Ƶiê)Jkí:¼Ω3ÃzjWÝ„|†rвávĀÜΛ°λöyÅÍ`mΣ×>K$λÜ—∍¯zÏΔ!#äy½´`в²!ÚÉ¡]5мô₃^Íp÷‰Ê)ûEîTº8E&sÙγüíθ4®₄ñтšиćÙA4ºÚIÜζ∍õ+¦ôι«$ι<yf·¶ê‹žƵ=v™>jg¥¢¦ŽнhΔÐŽÎΩć7∞ñè₄ćDç¥ƒ¨=ŽαxO,š
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVHbbhJRFP2VKa2QpsWm0kbj0DFim1h88MXEBy2UQRBaBcIAkbYPkymWasQr0fQahlp6v4BAy2VosvcMjyfjL5wfoSdq4tPeWVnZ67JFnxTq@X0Jp/M5lYuCl5cCLzh7mLONSryHZxBv47zcLSGSfMUn4skIowY4u2Qf5bx8wB@KcvYIZ2M0EUoOrD4wOiGL4Byy3xx@NmOhsuq2CcJf4tJINJYYiUo@MRz4NzivIPJ/YDHuC0eCSf/8/40Tew66um1q4/pKkMrfyC9sxvDMTRXFRTZopvjQCseg4ge8mrTgHn7xRKGZwkwKWvh90ejAjtXVb3SwQJWVe1jAIypv3aBKhh04dvkWqdzo1sJ4OOiex5O70CYHDlxemHuKW1TeXqJyIW5WUE3pMm6SDTgnLayn8S3mZl@THfwhPBpgyCaV83Q1B2cL@Ink@/rxZxo0qM6aFaj04Tq@A3Vm3GxjlSrLHszF8ILK5/h@EFtTePoEmnemrBKusWBtPCGXY3DK7GH5t2Ko5qWexbX7Y9DE9WnmoM5ksDYEJaySBhwNkIYzHYQLqOMhC2J0urWJFKtEmHsJu1CEkqGZWojk8bOh4UdyoGdvsyqxjPtMQc9O4h7sdr/C/oShkfKbx8OG2mMv7F0D) This answer was posted on the same day that I created Duocentehexaquinquagesimal. Happy birthday!

Comment: [594 bytes](https://tio.run/##lVFLCkIxDDxQyJwgzEUeb6GCIIILwfPXJmlfiwurIZQ0n5lMe36ebo/r63IvRbdNqRTbTcRddaebCEidDDUlAHXOw9yOcphHqG6KKESR7rUVDStvNsDBXuAA9gHOwHBy5KytKIkVZdB9ofqTySwb6pkME61lFNISwoW4TrR@bwjd47UpGPsmf6TbVA7GStaLST1EHsGn1Laoi@7br3/xhyct5Q0) brainfuck program generated by [bfbrute](https://github.com/ksabry/bfbrute).

Comment: [560 bytes](https://tio.run/##pVFBDgIxCHwQYV5A@MhmD2piYkw8mOz7qwO0dvW2spuUAjMD9Pw83R7X7XJvTRcXfrbYqur@9leXL4Nr2DgxpWg/ANtdbIog6BA0ZgZPBvqGUsl7/L1ubiYwgqTscFQNowc1/mHOMTPmg786x2d9JDBNTVah0iUCwuPMtAw/k0yThQC2UhuVruzR1hgl3mo3TChpwQ@sqbUX)

Comment: @ovs thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/sjoerdpennings/brasca), <s>72</s> 67 bytes

I really should add string compression...

```
l`uoY ot yadhtrib yppaH`58S[$:om{]xl`ACSARB raeD `L[$o{]x8p21S[$o{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7V9vGEv/fn2ILabGLDSaPhnAxLZD0hjYJOZie2x4ONWtrjZVKWkVaxfik7VfPnVk9rJXW1io8OacNSLszv3nu7O7In4kJ955s@8EX2/V5IEg4C9vEpWLSGAfcJcJ2GUlfOYz58eOAehb8k7zAv@C/S9ZIHoiAjtiQjv5qNEYODUNyENBwRA/x950GgZ@VlZW@gAFtErBLOxQsCAlQIZ9oYNOhw0IYIAdabEwGA9uzxWDQDJkzbu005Av8WZU05MSMTPYSB2@EckCPnJ2rzyk866qPhsqjOY/9gJEpAwbUsr1Lwj6xALSGv9KQjCYUZEW@PxYZBzBk4HKLAd2fqROyHO73ts@sju0RiwqaPbbHxOPSBDAdmG3YIRVi1mztZENy9GHAAKcD@fkMRNlsne3sdLbOlUljHpBBmwwIMGVe5LKACtYskCow0jBDe4WRI5Cp@uYMWbZLT4s4VMtsUN9nntXkgdWMCbda2XAGOquSHLxkrtXXFJ0oMc6QMY/4YATBLDJjomAf6qCqZoN0RNlGpxM7JFPbcUgoOPgAhd/EhJEhGPwvJojPQ1vY3Ct43HRiO2zgcO6HQPTzPwpFRkboEOiwSMrnyDxQCeCIQfKm7KWj2KHycsvnEHmOPYIoAdtmwuhHCO6r4q6@j8IJgYlD4Ci4hCbNk0WgDwMG8QDpM20cnfOWskXxfZ76J@pEjPDxPGKQk4YLvk944K9LmaDbyEGtxYIMuRCQqoDzUrEG8bgq6WwvZIFoduMh1QIaIcAZKv/Fks8BlIUHu8rsXGDB/TRxFhNNRlYNs4CJKPBynleOxGRIDhiyiWO3gKZSBdzPC38HMLupxvoQxggoXTwyTCETg/RhYpL0TxVf@pT0ICbpiiZd0TRVzhUUYy3OHupmD8uzcz6Xx74WJi6oDWBMdjclkRKCsYwtvdzduuKWSQ9beqV0ExOe4HocMq3I8k3RqXJ80hGtjJb0FiTlMO9STPQOG78r0k1cDV425yxyoRk5sOBKanKFILhCEAf0QZrFdaOVsRpGtmPFD4v8BHN9tbDBJwOoO5SaQ30JC6PDPkZcMMU6WBykyxkkH@66uEKVKwVcfAo1Api1RHqPdMuFRGlUp0e2lFHSR8o4e4upFWQtAksFQXc7W4lXXWVeMlFPPnXDVDGtMtg8g/NaDMA7AiyiJCM1MyyqJs7knHOYlCKqnpKOxFly@nIZ1lYqNX0aRKzatj3yeDmni9rmyA8rgTCljxOrySfe1MA9SH8GGcslNLiESPAEbF98uWfCMhC2NBv@jIzJ7hhU7lGX7ZXfjsguhs1eo3HKIZ5wcwOhPYwu2ySCvDW2NkcYasCFWphvxpujDRwaOnxKLD71CI@EH4lkeLg5CiUwG/dFyHMwkBIPBi6FuniQmDAGAIbIbb0SJ0uwZZXkyhfnIuJ/EFhqZ9SawMZlSGa@T19fPNvunz3a4e7n8yvnYv@wv39yAJs99pJcvDl7xOHptv94qy9//ZLs6uJ8Rw4wccWZFPOcS/0863xaS1MkeQvw5Wj5d5wkc1CzknhX5tjcm3xSDGaqeTOfyJM605A9LyaPZIyyj1vooKUHq0Qu0LuQP/fUQndJjupqwi@ntXwR3i3ni1IMbJmT2zIg99ic3GMDck/MyT0xIPfUnNxTA3LPzMk9MyD3gzm5HwzIPTcn99yA3LY5uW0Dci/Myb0wIOfUcGOTsHhTg56J57EacWFi3Fc1AsMk0KwakWFi3pc1fNkkNiY13MXEm1/X8RcTh/m1FkETip9XdsjqSzYKGNYUpsTTR1gtdkwy9j/I5si7Bpt1EzYBspHL3Yk8BNbxofMVWF/tSjAmg3CvYuPeRJ44N4dtQgGl3kILJLRbjfKCLQWIV3uosSY0qBR87WJtqWOoR8DawtmoAi9KIU/IKsqZ9a3z1jJCSkW1jjuxskbeUtwB@7j/47lz9YXY19EP9i3rlh1A57Lr1MBPO4ivHw3xdkLcA8iOCcjvEeTbyBG278zuAeT3JiA348Qi2CV4j2V/skPdbvT2wW5umqD9VqqUW5HD7wHjtyYQ/0SIr6587i1K1LdsdSOzhzKAPgbXQVhmjpeNG2PY@CW/hsCgSVstXZI@sMXUhm1wjaz0L4J@d3x6o5j/NVHXdzIfvnt5D/b8zgTf34jv@OQe4P1tAm@A8H6/F3x/Aj6N9/W1m/gScIrAfXk@z@dn3vtLS4X8fQMQMFDPUMvlwJzL0ITLvuSSXuWYCaPeNZhJc6Dnc1CDj5E8beSTnPsvOJRROKQXBJWEd5CwFeEVqzznB1H4eAmHr8089DojS6j/o6KeX9OZAk9v7kxRpePpDUwoSeOiNC7/pKof4yMmomUZX5p9lTFSbJKEAb63Gb6CouWdXXLwWY2vrs6N8fkV@iOe7AcK9X7h8sgTpjs4b76D67bjqUv2cMY2uhk7va@w0wPSw3JfuKY//CiTZdzqlTRVdDtbj5@b@l3WF9aEfWbxXKFlAOCbbI2b38dWJm3NWUZyY2vC8hGyDKfUl4YWU05swdyQcO/ayfzWM/7QQL4TaVMu0kVKTALG7lbG0a0rYnQdlWnvc0p67KMeR9zDddPLlAnuEhMO795PMMZCgSKt4z/UKMIui2IsdoCk4QDZrK1tfOC2J9l5rXkiyw6@sPVhcdIbYZqDZJJLfbkrvWR29YleHeUgeAN12Ik6oOwTBIjYNqb8JPc1O7rzcUWodpKildYJRa7FYgGUePJejzzdTrph8e/dHnn2fPE85cQRWJxJJHjjL6cD6Gq5j/Jyz/vnYg001@9M7q4q9ouvlhogN6rFvpLlrw1EAqu6ZF/qdyXav@dpmxTWJot6iUuEXH7zOn0tSc@0DJHNPnE01ztJh2RgmeSZ3xKclwtx5nPKVZxTrko5pVHlBmpH1E2LqTkTONo8NnA0Lo9aZB8Hdo3v9w@PjpLuyCqvm7cilFqWF7YjFEQp9zprLyPwRw5pjibqNVCrDWFt9dbWDCx9vFBUkyC4f2mz4KsjtKcKnWTQh2vgvHFriPlusZgP1bgaw84F1sTzIfdEwB3ys8On1QrZRYW8YWEIdTS97RsQVN8urZW4tvSUmImq67Yb7aEu/gvmka3vd6OOvYerjp680vkYgVvfgSJ6vQeribU/1kATB0xMGfMewtYS9YXV5Qj/93Ad6Cd0oFMWuDZuzBo3kxTxSzF2ZQuT2nIVAUA@tGQLMXXIh8j1KxK71DrqtVupj3ILQiWiD4joF0CB1dwUCuuwTo@D2j9Tze2XjBt@yliPXUdlt27A7gzZ/Q/bXjuyZ7bcr11Wd1zzfoNF79INlrJT6mydV1hokVSZUPke88pmWq205wVpYUm@LVn3blVUE086XN7VU/h2z6xT6NSQZvy1n6TZUHcu8bctUgo/YPJAJsw@c8VPKZN2qHKnvb43Wt9cv3qKn8XYAkrDMZlOmAdbfA6MAxlVwgabAtsx7N6tiv7oev1W6ucvGZpjZC17COS5si0a5sm81ISVgCt0Kqy@lVco6ceexY88jVIguxoxX5Bf2WzIIfFgr00QRL4ofDNVzubJxFfyH0jbaMiCOKt97rL4I9kp8wSZBty7bONJMJ@CcQhw4ircuJReeXVycnyyQ3TTC3ev8YTsM/ANSNcuFQMAVzyEz4kQfwdwlDhu8tlDo@7GYT5WCQHwMc0OY@k97zWOKmlvaRWiwYihr8dY3qzSqj3bAuL6AJ3TpmWyWnKJPsvklohdW@RqceuLulBM/Pnyfw)

### Explanation

```
l`uoY ot yadhtrib yppaH`                                                 - Push "Happy birthday to You\n"
                        58S[$:om{]x                                      - Output it twice followed by "Happy birthday"
                                   l`ACSARB raeD `                       - Push " Dear BRASCA\n"
                                                  L[$o{]x                - Output it
                                                         8p              - Shift the stack so the top is "Happy birthday to You"
                                                           21S[$o{]      - Output that.
```

Comment: is BRASCA a golfing language?

Comment: Not really, I just made it for fun. String compression would definitely be nice to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 112 bytes

All this jumping eats up the bytes, I'm afraid.

```
→1→2→3→1→2→3→1→4→3→1→2'!'!¤'Happy birthday'↑¤' to you'↑¤','¶↑¤', dear Barrel'↑
```

Basically, it defines a bunch of functions whose purpose is to implicitly print strings and calls them in the appropriate order before exiting. The second `!` (the first one is a string for ending the song) exits the program so that barrel doesn't continue executing the program. If the `!` were not there, barrel would implicitly print 'Happy birthday' and then exit, seeing that the `↑` instruction doesn't have any more location pointers to pop, and therefore "pops" to the program that ran barrel.

Answer (score 1):

## [Quipu](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Quipu), <s>123</s> 115 bytes

```
'H'D't[][][]
'a'e'o/\/\/\
'p'a' 2&1&2&
'p'r'Y[][][]
'y' 'o/\/\/\
' 'Q'u
'B'u\n
'i'i/\
'r'p
't'u
'h\n
'd
'a
'y
' 
/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVltc9s2Ev7OX7FhpyYZJ5Kdj6rlXu1cp@21Se7SmZsb272BKUhiQ5EsANrRaPTbc7sLgCb1Ykt2PHOjSSwCD/bl2cUSWOlU5OJLv/9BaCNhXtYK0nIkISvATKX9rmVqsrIAUYx4MCuq2niEfXCQHrwt81wo0Nmk0DAVNxJMCdcSpE5FJUdwm5kpjFqgIJtVpUJxZe8jak@lH0gR5KTOaiOuc9n7QSkxP6vHY6mC8vpPnIXfBNohPxtZjDT8UFULo@aLnwsjVaUk/h9/EErjn0Z8b6zK2dncSB1/6FWqnPQm0vBzkiTLVJh0ukiFllDJgV3798@prMiO4WmlssLkRRzaGZBKlWoA4WElScxvUmsxkUnAAjI5gJYljRgYnkIjqAVopMEhrl2X918SN5Kf39fm/fisrNHjzTLflS4q4wxJC5PlMkhzoTWs@BPPrPwBfDS4dpI0RK5BEs@3FbEw80rC71MlxQiG0IrLxT@K0lwFIzkGUVX5PNbMOqrgv8nAgi/s/wy@QgmL4AYTwrBAPYBfM20ukBqaepfl0O9DrTF7MJeykSyMZrg2yir1Qq0bV96iOGEYstKFOcFtjJK6zs2g44l176rrH@KtRxSfX7NCahiXiEunsIAcw4DicshxAl2Wf12cT4UiEbkzBeOHT0dBNobYuQtDdjJBEmiU1vZyWUxwo5zCERwcsLj4KIEXQwgvwxC/Evh2iuGF2Mo8gda65L7JRiDPJb1M/3uaYfpXAsPjLDwcwjEbYx9Rb1s6RysHg44U8talARJjaB2NvKtnFFm0M7DE0oQJGn99oGFwaBUGjdo3mKxNXD31PUzk3NPV@BiGy6CJ7f3Q18dLlOtHUVmWtgOXYdh8aBwozhLrpM9x6wgNrwfJWQ/HRE2LW5hROcEx3r/RRUT5MapnlbUZlXjzUe6ru3zmJ6s5cVYTN/@SY6I1aK9Cy14fB@2VOBKGTuMfT9T4UeZ7qkwHQCkPSFKKqfU2m2SGbLhjxfLUZeaA7bQJ11ZEmnhfdNUfBcvuEJqa9kxp9z9@wR3uJP/tPslrYh8SCi/h@MhJ/vbr28zivfxvHiF/FYwb92gDtvPILu1qGyGteZcR2dfJIFq2EmcPvoweToJio8DosogcwGwBGA/oPzHdfy52TXbPwuETNVK1fF9xsYw/v4J5Qh4SO/Nkj23@@nmseL2fFS@fx4qX@1nR3yHTXDo@3lQ8gu1ZifvPQ05/V3KWnar11e34dr8gDb@CFee/zLwd1oYhFbt9rPj@iVY4A/bQeLJDcp48Bzcne1LzLAE62T1APl1PdyDs9DlsPf1/IOx0f8K@e5Qdu/s5eKKfP4l839L5zRNVnlfzPTXCozSuS1vXuHQfd4dM81JLvDnh/Za0gchzuLYqt99WIPPXzA2Xk32NXrIgQVenLVdzykx7VbZa/KXKXe222ccird@NdXiSZEmoVUlTq8IqxsdKZTfCSKC@QccFbqGg8b5H4S0frDcd/AU6o2OvPSN395e/lmaJOytrvlGH60jUxUiduHjZ/smmbs5jmijtps@i1SuhbtumKCQOhUSW@Y38BQmKCwQW84T5oSh1i6LlDSwdJ9zGa27vWFoy11Gi7@h5ecteb3SPukm6Rsme98uQGlQF/gsvw15oU0hBZRTfQuj7FDe5pLxs6eXXs29LvLAI9ItaO@WNbHo/3bym9TFKTly/R6SfXHMIfb9qbuvUG@m47yNdsLcFDAbUYbFzd7Hl24Sfs158whnff2LuGx2YuzTaM8L2o/SnrNLcAdV4SeaFLOFPDA77Pha5ljw0zopMT3mQ5d/DCDVnXjR4erDy2kyxjMBKmhJPHdddk8CXCIVpM7TMrbH0QJIw@VnyELkbWfXvoydkWGNzK9F4jCvKmOLGjxyRTZZ5cNFAN5rqUHoV5VofHQzrw1JgVsDuFbOGJfO7SHd2HrOJgVFzZDW22GMu0nbVCuWxcHXwmv92DB8XscCJVUVucAf631dSCVNSE/SvOsMaA@aWOshGTrAEv4JJaWxTWlAo@FcAerrm2ghp2055f4s6eDgTDMiirCdTfDNM6hm1eunFAiXbSL8FcB5Y0v1xqUqaFyKukqbFftANHafKvZvBtVwqTHyqus1uNqqWga1x7SpsFSZ7pfu5KCJjKz5XC0AEvkLp9WdKy3STBl6wc3UvP3e1nRXY1oeXrxl8XhaIlj3aldTqphYvJ@ydMuWaQ03urScEbsprqX4sFdLd@b2iJaW13m0Te8EmmLeCf96I75hhnD9OErB567C/S1shm5rLlLQqceymbe/dHQhcteXC27yibEKgkXj3IHynTi6CFbUgsezjsOXbLeMzBCu4k3r36nqgPlOR7Z5eeLY5EnnA2qGFPuIa6RV45rAnGD4I20YtP3uhGPRautrizy@rWC/fYVePO6vwptINIOba5QvXvUruNrVdxivOSkwAUWxa5U5U/q23FeA30FaA2wBb531GbgU0qbgV0bxStiL8e6QD8L@8LegISL9YDpW4DcPwS/RT9DYyF1f0CSIRyajsX9IniCp8hDcHxwdvDuhBRf/xsDnebhoYRP@M6iA6i@rLIoiyKKNBFVVBZGh8SqMjFI3LEBz0L7@g3uWX/wE)

#### Explanation

Each pair of columns in a Quipu program is a "thread." Execution proceeds from the top of each thread to the bottom, left to right from one thread to the next. Each thread also stores a value, which can be referenced by other threads.

- Thread 0 outputs `Happy Birthday`  with a trailing space and sets its value to that string.
- Thread 1 sets its value to `Dear Quipu` with a trailing newline.
- Thread 2 outputs `to You` with a trailing newline and sets its value to that string.
- Thread 3 outputs the value of thread 0, then outputs the value of thread 2.
- Thread 4 outputs the value of thread 0, then outputs the value of thread 1.
- Thread 5 outputs the value of thread 0, then outputs the value of thread 2.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>120</s> 114 bytes

```
(load library
(d x(q(Happy Birthday 
(d y(join(concat x(q(to You)))spc
y 
y
(join(concat x(q(Dear tinylisp)))spc
y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1BCoMwEIXhvad4y8k1xEWv0OU0KXQkZNI4gnP6qFiEbh8f7zcpnmWpvVNWTsjyatx8oISNvqAH1@oYpdknsePcnWaVAopaItvFTPHUNYSApcbhcMfDqf7Q9OYG@wVv2/sO)

Comment: Refactoring a bit gives [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoAgDER3vqJj@Q3j4O7EWMHEGkIR68DXIxhz073cyymnGvnOrWEUChB5K1SqwQALXoirxVM4oZfkSTtZKOcKExc9AlVrV3tnP@YOh6ACTh7jer4@71RA/xPjWnsB).

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 51 bytes

```bash
set Happy\ Birthday to You
<<.
$@
$@
$1 Dear zsh
$@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3jYtTSxQ8EgsKKmMUnDKLSjJSEisVSvIVIvNLuWxs9LhUHMDIUMElNbFIAagTyIVohZoAMwkA)

Beats vanilla shell by one byte, despite having a one-byte longer name!

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 45 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__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-KXv-KBv-KCmeKGp-KGpeKIoOKEguKnu-KWs-KHoeKKouKHjOKZrcKk4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pe04pew4pah4ouV4omN4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4piH4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqX4oin4oi14omh4oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oqQ4ouF4oqZ4oipwrDijIXijZziioPiqr7iipPii5TijaLirJrijaPijaTihqzihqvimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ7iuK7ihpAiCgojIEFsbCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIFVpdWEgdXNlcyBmb3IgcHJldHR5LXByaW50aW5nLgojIENhbiBiZSByZW1vdmVkIGlmIG5lY2Vzc2FyeS4KCkRSQVdJTkcg4oaQICLila3ilIDilbfila_in6bin6fijJzijJ_ilZPilZ_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-KHoTPil4viiKkow7cyNSnih6EyNDDih6E4MCIKIyBFbmNvZGUgdG8gYSAuc2JjcyBmaWxlOgojICAgRW5jb2RlVUEgUGF0aFVBCiMgRGVjb2RlIGEgLnNiY3MgZmlsZToKIyAgIERlY29kZVNCQ1MgUGF0aFNCQ1MK)</sup>

```
⍥(&p⊂"Happy Birthday ")4.,"Dear Uiua""to You"
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4o2lKCZw4oqCIkhhcHB5IEJpcnRoZGF5ICIpNC4sIkRlYXIgVWl1YSIidG8gWW91Igo=)

### Explanation

```
⍥(&p⊂"Happy Birthday ")4.,"Dear Uiua""to You"
                                     "to You" # push string "to You" to stack
                          "Dead Uiua"         # push string "Dear Uiua" to stack
                         ,                    # duplicate 2nd-to-top stack element
                        .                     # duplicate top stack element
⍥(                    )4                      # repeat this function 4 times:
     "Happy Birthday "                        # push string "Happy Birthday " to stack
    ⊂                                         # join end-to-end
  &p                                          # print to stdout with newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript, 56 bytes

Thanks, professorfish!

```
"Happy Birthday ":h"to You\n"+:s s h"dear Golfscript\n"s
```

Output:

```
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday dear Golfscript
Happy Birthday to You
```

Comment: You don't need to concatenate them; they'll all be printed anyway

Comment: and you seem to do `"Happy Birthday ":h;h` - why do you need to pop the value and then push it again? `"Happy Birthday ":h` will have the same effect AFAIK. same for `:s;s`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 73

Run this in the console

```
for(h="",i=4;i;)h+='\nHappy Birthday '+(--i-1?'to You':'Dear JavaScript')
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to just declare the happy birthday 4 times than to loop it.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell 92 (fixed)

```
$a="happy birthday to you";$a;$a;write-host -no  $a.TrimEnd('to you');"y dear powershell" ;$a
```

this one is longer than the other PS solution but is unique and actually out puts the correct string

### OLD  -Powershell- - 62

```
$a="happy birthday to you";$a;$a;write "$a dear powershell";$a
```

Comment: It looks to me like that will print the third line as "happy birthday to you dear powershell", which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 136

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){static int i=0;std::cout<<"Happy Birthday "<<(i==2?"Dear C++":"to You")<<std::endl;return ++i<4?main():0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## B - 109

(caveat: arguably not valid B, difficult to say - works [with this](https://github.com/Leushenko/ybc))

```
main()v(4,"Happy Birthday to You   HDear B");v(i,s){s[5]=i&5?'u':134744072;s[6]=&-247;i?puts(s)&v(i-1,s):0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

EcmaScript 6 - 64 о_О

```
[1,1,0,1].map(i=>"Happy Birthday "+(i?"to you":"ES6")).join("\n")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not completely follow the spec: you need to have "dear" before the language name, you have to write out "JavaScript", as per the other JS answers, and you have to provide a way of outputting the result so it can be a stand-alone program (`console.log` in this case.)

Comment: Than that's the fix (83):
`alert([1,1,0,1].map(i=>"Happy Birthday "+(i?"to you":"Dear EcmaScript")).join("\n"))`

Comment: By the way, solution http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39770/32091 does not do any output and uses latest evaluation output in console like mine.

Comment: True, but that one should also have its own method of output.

Answer (score 0):

### ><> 76 Bytes

Since it wasn't here already...

```
0>"Happy Birthda"{1+:}3-?vv
v^?=1l<;?=5}:{a"uoY oT y"<>"y Dear ><>"a
>{{o} ^
```

Answer (score 0):

## JS 70 Bytes

```
alert([c=(a="Happy Birthday")+" to You",c,a+" Dear JS",c].join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 68 bytes

```
(1...4).map{print("Happy Birthday "+($0==3 ?"dear Swift":"to You"))}
```

also differently:

```
print({$0+$1+$0+$1+$0+"dear Swift"+$0+$1}("\nHappy Birthday ","to You"))
```

with 71 bytes

Comment: Another 70-byte alternative: `for i in 1...4{print("Happy Birthday "+(i==3 ?"Dear Swift":"to You"))}`

Answer (score 0):

## HPPPL (HP Prime Programming Language), 88

```
n:=char(10);a:="Happy Birthday ";b:="To You";c:="Dear HPPPL";d:=a+b+n;print(d+d+a+c+n+d)
```

Result:

[image: Happy Birthday To You HPPPL]

HPPPL is the programming language for the HP Prime color graphing calculator/CAS. An emulator is available at the HP website.

Answer (score 0):

## Sprects, 49 bytes

```
.12121Dear Sprects\n12.1Happy Birthday .2to You\n
```

[Try it here](http://dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stringy](https://github.com/m654z/Stringy), 78 bytes

```
(Happy birthday );a to you;p;p;^ to you!dear Stringy;p;^ dear Stringy!to you;p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 70 bytes

Mouse isn't very skilled at [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity). :(

```
$H"Happy Birthday "@
$Y"to you!"@
#H;#Y;#H;#Y;#H;"Dear Mouse!"#H;#Y;$
```

The exclamation points print newlines, not themselves, and the `$H` and `$Y` are functions, not variables, because poor Mouse can't comprehend strings.

### MUSYS, MUsic-SYStem, Mouse's predecessor, 93 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday to you!Happy Birthday to you!Happy birthday dear MUSYS!Happy Birthday to you"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Staq](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Staq), <s>67</s> 66 chars

```
{h"Happy Birthday "}{T"To You"}{D"Dear Staq"}{N&iiqi,;}hTNhTNhDNhT
```

Result:

```
Executing D:\codegolf\Happy Birthday Staq.staq

Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday To You
Happy Birthday Dear Staq
Happy Birthday To You

Execution complete.
>
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 70 Bytes

```
a="Happy Birthday ";b=a+"to You\n";c=a+b;d=c+c+a+"Dear JavaScript\n"+c
```

**Best answer JavaScript answer so far!**

```
a="Happy Birthday ";
b=a+"to You\n";
c=a+b;                         // Create string "Happy Birthday to You\n"
d=c+c+a+"Dear JavaScript\n"+c  // Create song
```

Implementation:

```
a="Happy Birthday ";b=a+"to You\n";c=a+b;d=c+c+a+"Dear JavaScript\n"+c
alert(d);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: You're not allowed to leave output in a variable. You have to write a full program which prints it or a function which returns it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Edited Processing.js](https://github.com/Khan/processing-js) 80 bytes

```
var a="\nhappy birthday to you";print(a+a+"\nHappy birthday processing.js"+a);
```

Processing JS is a language that is fun but I am lazy and use an edited version that also is ungolfable.
[Try it online](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/new-program/5992443128643584) Println was used so you don't have to open the console :P

Khanacademy version

Comment: Ah, it's the Khan Academy version. Perhaps you should mention that somewhere (also, I believe the source code is [here](https://github.com/Khan/processing-js))

Answer (score 0):

## C, 74 bytes

```C
i=5;main(){while(--i)printf("Happy Birthday %s\n",i-2?"to You":"Dear C");}
```

**Detailed**

```C
void main()
{
    int i = 5;

    while (--i > 0)
    {
        printf("Happy Birthday %s\n",
        i!=2 ? "to You" : "Dear C" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to write a program, not a function. Change `f()` to `main()` and it should be OK (but one character longer than [V-X's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39761/11006)).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## C\C++ Preprocessor, <s>244</s> 224 bytes

[**Live in C**](http://ideone.com/dDTwCj)

[**Live in C++**](http://ideone.com/5qCEWm)

```C
#define A "to"
#define B "You"
#define C "C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define C "C++"
#endif
#define D "Dear"
#define E "Happy Birthday"
#define H printf("%s %s %s \n",E,A,B)
int main(){H;H;printf("%s %s %s \n",E,D,C);H;return 0;}
```

Comment: You don't need the "return 0"... Also, too many whitespaces. Why do you split E and F? ...

Comment: @user202729 just made E and F the same thing, return is needed for it to work in C++

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 92 bytes

```
#include<iostream> 
int main(int c){for(c=4;c--;)std::cout<<"Happy Birthday "<<(c-1?"To You":"Dear C++")<<"\n";}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#U87MS84pTUm1ycwvLilKTcy1@5@ZV6KQm5iZpwFiJGtWp@UXaSTbmlgn6@paaxaXpFhZJeeXltjYKHkkFhRUKjhlFpVkpCRWKijZ2Ggk6xraK4XkK0TmlypZKbmkJhYpOGtrK2kCVcfkKVnX/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 72 bytes

```
@SET h=@ECHO Happy Birthday 
%h%to You
%h%to You
%h%Dear Batch
%h%to You
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 52 bytes

```
|`Happy Birthday `|A|`to You
`|BABABA`Dear Fourier
`AB
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=fGBIYXBweSBCaXJ0aGRheSBgfEF8YHRvIFlvdQpgfEJBQkFCQWBEZWFyIEZvdXJpZXIKYEFC)

Nothing particularly special except that it demonstrates that you can have newlines in string prints.

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 69 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"VR{.M}v&,6>[$_]"dear Braingolf
"R!&@!&@v&@c&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fySOxoKBSwSmzqCQjJbFSoSRfITK/lEspLKhaz7e2TE3HzC5aJT5WKSU1sUjBCaaPSylIUc0BiMrUHJLVHP7/BwA)

### Explanation

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"
```

Pushes "Happy Birthday to You\n" to the stack

```
VR{.M}
```

Creates a 2nd stack and duplicates the contents of the first stack to it, in reverse order

```
v&,
```

Switches to the 2nd stack and flips the entire stack

```
6>[$_]
```

Drops the last 7 items from the 2nd stack

```
"dear Braingolf
"
```

Pushes "dear Braingolf\n" to the 2nd stack

```
R!&@!&@
```

Prints the contents of the first stack twice

```
v&@
```

Prints the contents of the 2nd stack

```
c&@
```

Prints the contents of the first stack

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 813 bytes

I guess this belongs here now too! Loops haven't been added to the language yet, so this is the best I can manage.

```
+53@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+552@66+1@6:5/1+3@6/1+52@6:5+1/1+551@6+1@6:5+3/1+552@6:5/1+551@6:1/1+551@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+553@6:5/1+3@6:5+3/1+552@6:3/1+552@6:5/1+3@6:5+3/1+54@6:3/1+552@6:5+53@6:1/1+1@6:5+3@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+552@66+1@6:5/1+3@6/1+52@6:5+1/1+551@6+1@6:5+3/1+552@6:5/1+551@6:1/1+551@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+553@6:5/1+3@6:5+3/1+552@6:3/1+552@6:5/1+3@6:5+3/1+54@6:3/1+552@6:5+53@6:1/1+1@6:5+3@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+552@66+1@6:5/1+3@6/1+52@6:5+1/1+551@6+1@6:5+3/1+552@6:5/1+551@6:1/1+551@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+553@6:5/1+3@6+4@6:2/1+551@6:5+2/1+55@6:5+1/1+552@6:5/1+3@6:4/1+52@6:5+53@6:5+3/1+55@6:5+1/1+551@6:5+51@6:5+2/1+55@6:5+52@66:4/1+553@6:1/1+1@6:5+3@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+552@66+1@6:5/1+3@6/1+52@6:5+1/1+551@6+1@6:5+3/1+552@6:5/1+551@6:1/1+551@6:5+2/1+55@6:4/1+553@6:5/1+3@6:5+3/1+552@6:3/1+552@6:5/1+3@6:5+3/1+54@6:3/1+552@6:5+53@6
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##7ZGxDoAgDER/xb2DFiiDE7@iTiasDn490ioCwcnNxK3wjrtrWLZ5XSbv9xCAtLMjgeoRiOJoZFDOWkAm8RgVfKlEiMIjOjHopBepkPHWtMY6e1aPa5uCmhqefTngiv/bv2kPXEw9SVNKuYzJFahcvS7FtDGTbYr8T/9cCNTh0CEd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 49 bytes

Since the other Pyth answer is quite outdated and *non-competing* has been removed [per meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges), here is a newer answer:

```
K"Happy Birthday "J+K"to You\n"+*J2+K"Dear Pyth"J
```

**[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22Happy+Birthday+%22J%2BK%22to+You%5Cn%22%2B%2aJ2%2BK%22Dear+Pyth%22J&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 50 bytes

```
K+"Happy Birthday to You"b+++KK++<K15"Dear Pyth"bK
```

**[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22Happy+Birthday+to+You%5Cn%22%2B%2B%2BKK%2B%3CK15%22Dear+Pyth%5Cn%22K&debug=0)**

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
‰║M─╬RS‘ūΖTtŗQQ"8Ν¼ģ^ļ&NZøe‘O
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMDMwJXUyNTUxTSV1MjUwMCV1MjU2Q1JTJXUyMDE4JXUwMTZCJXUwMzk2VHQldTAxNTdRUSUyMjgldTAzOUQlQkMldTAxMjMlNUUldTAxM0MlMjZOWiVGOGUldTIwMThP,v=0.12)

Answer (score 0):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 43 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
３［to You¶｝Dear Canvas¶）«∑Happy Birthday ４＊×
```

[Try it online!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjEzJXVGRjNCdG8lMjBZb3UlQjYldUZGNUREZWFyJTIwQ2FudmFzJUI2JXVGRjA5JUFCJXUyMjExSGFwcHklMjBCaXJ0aGRheSUyMCV1RkYxNCV1RkYwQSVENw__)

With notes (not valid code, as Canvas does not support comments):

```
３［to You¶｝                                      Push the string "to You\n" to the stack three times
            Dear Canvas¶                          Push the string "Dear Canvas\n" to the stack
                        ）                        Compress the stack to an array
                          «                       Shift the array once to the left
                           ∑                      Join all strings in the array to one string
                            Happy Birthday ４＊   Push the string "Happy Birthday " repeated four times vertically to the stack
                                               ×  Concatenate the second object in the stack to the first object in the stack
                                                  Print the object at the top of the stack (implicit)
```

Comment: [40 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjEzJXVGRjNCdG8lMjBZb3UldUZGNUREZWFyJTIwQ2FudmFzJXVGRjA5JUFCSGFwcHklMjBCaXJ0aGRheSUyMCV1RkYxNCV1RkYwQSVENw__,v=5)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 55 bytes

```
L,"Happy Birthday "dddB]"To You"ddV"Dear Add++"GBCBcB+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR8kjsaCgUsEps6gkIyWxUkEpJSXFKVYpJF8hMr8UyAlTcklNLFJwTEnR1lZyd3J2SnbSzvv/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 82 Bytes

```
h="Happy Birthday";y='to You';d="Dear Python";print h,y,'\n',h,y,'\n',h,d,'\n',h,y
```

Still getting my head around slicing...

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 54 bytes

```
Print=>4&("Happy Birthday "+2&"To You"'"Dear Attache")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM6/E1s5ETUPJI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVJBSdtITSkkXyEyv1RJXcklNbFIwRGiS0nz/38A)

### Explanation

```
2&"To You"'"Dear Attache"
2&"To You"                  resizes "To You" into a 2-length array
          '"Dear Attache"   concatenate with "Dear Attache"

                            result: ["To You", "To You", "Dear Attache"]


"Happy Birthday "+_         Adds this string to each element
                            result: ["Happy Birthday To You", "Happy Birthday To You", "Happy Birthday Dear Attache"]

4&(_)                       Resizes the array to size 4
                            result: ["Happy Birthday To You", "Happy Birthday To You", "Happy Birthday Dear Attache", "Happy Birthday To You"]

Print=>_                    Prints each member on its own line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jamal](http://verhas.com/peter/progs/perl/jamal/), 57 characters

```
{@for _(///dear jamal/0)Happy Birthday {@if/_/_/to You}
}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jamal.pl birthday.jam 
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday to You
Happy Birthday dear jamal
Happy Birthday to You
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 56 bytes

```
≔Happy Birthdayη≔ to YouτＰ⁺ητ↓Ｐ⁺ητ↓Ｐ⁺η”↶ G↗5▶h…≡-⌕”↓Ｐ⁺ητ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DySOxoKBSwSmzqCQjJbFSSUchQ9OaCyapUJKvEJlfChQtAYr6luaUZAYUZeaVaDimpGhkgERBwvllqRpWLvnleaSoKUBWo6TgkppYpOAMdZ0Skcb@//9ftywHAA) (Link to the verbose version.)

It wasn't fair that Charcoal still hadn't its own birthday party...

Comment: [47](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DySOxoKBSwSmzqCQjJbFSSUchQ9OaCyrpmJKikaGjoKRQkq8QmV8ak6ekqaNQApQPKMrMK9HAxsqAMZQUXFITixScoRbGFCkhq/7//79uWQ4A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 54 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday "~s"to You"+~mP?P?sP"Dear Noether"P?mP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/X8kjsaCgUsEps6gkIyWxUkGprlipJF8hMr9USbsuN8A@wL44QMklNbFIwQ@iRSnAPjfg/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 93 bytes

```
1 FOR I=1 TO 4:PRINT"Happy Birthday ";:IF I=3 THEN PRINT"Dear MBASIC"ELSE PRINT"to You"
2 NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 45 bytes

```
"Happy Birthday to You"·E<"Dear MathGolf"+\]n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/JI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVKhJF8hMr9U6dB2Vxsll9TEIgVfoFJ3oFIl7ZjYvP//AQ)

Comment: wow this challenge is 4 years old now

Comment: I was surprised that there weren't any answers from some newer golfing languages, but I like these simple challenges. With some string compression this answer could be shorter, but I haven't implemented that yet.

Answer (score 0):

## A0A0 - 309 bytes

```
A0A0
A0C3G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1A0
A0P72P97P112P112P121P32P66P105P114P116P104P100P97P121P32G3A0
A0A1G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3A0
G-3
G1G4G7G4
A0A0
A0C3G1G1G1G1G1G1G1A0
A0P116P111P32P89P111P117P10G3A0
A0A1G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3A0
G-3
G-8G-8
P68P65
P101P48
P97P65
P114P48
P32P10
G-5G-14
```

### Explanation:

```
A0A0
A0C3G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1A0
A0P72P97P112P112P121P32P66P105P114P116P104P100P97P121P32G3A0
A0A1G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

Creates a loop which prints "Happy Birthday " and jumps every iteration.

```
G1G4G7G4
```

The positions the code should jump to each iteration.

```
A0A0
A0C3G1G1G1G1G1G1G1A0
A0P116P111P32P89P111P117P10G3A0
A0A1G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

Creates a loop which will print "to you" and jumps out of the loop after each iteration.

```
G-8G-8
```

More positions to jump to, but this time for the second loop (also acts as a sort of counter, adding an additional `G-8` would print "Happy Birthday " one more time).

```
P68P65
P101P48
P97P65
P114P48
P32P10
G-5G-14
```

Prints "Dear A0A0" and jumps back to the first loop.

[Test it here.](https://repl.it/repls/ShamelessProudWorker)

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 251 bytes

```
⇒:4+@:5+2/1+55@+2S-0@@S'+1@f2/1+52@F+5@F'+1@:4/1+6255@U-1@U'/6+1*@S-0@S'+1/1*@f2
⇒:5/1+3@
⇒/6+6366@/4+552@f2/67+55@/3+552@B+1@B'/6+1@
f1f3f1f3f1//3+6635@/3+551@:5+2/1+55@/3+6552@f2+/3+165@-6+355@/6++++55@/3+6551@:1+55@:5+2/1+55@:2+55@@/6+61*@/6+1@f1f3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xCsMwDEX3XCRQEVxJtgqeRIZcIOQAbcBQyNqhJ@jeI/YiruSUtgYb@f@nL623y3U9b9u91tfjmSNoTkABISUFmoej6twDamka6QRJJxdyNEHIsGVAXfoggAf1BueD1YU6j0zGsXppiLCIhmjp5JFy8jmB23@01LHlaFew8H6DuSL8ofBvPTf2HLASJekgwG4I2PkS1tP4X2cmf50T27NN9GG1vgE)

#### Explanation:

First, second and third lines are functions.
First line prints "Happy Birthday " (note the trailing space)
Second line prints a space (to golf it down)
Third line prints "to You\n"

Fourth line is the program. It simply calls functions and prints "Dear Cubically\n" on the third line.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 55 bytes

```
a"Happy birthday to you"3F6sK|6sR}a"Dear Gol><>"6sR{r~H
```

Voila, explanation coming soon!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P1HJI7GgoFIhKbOoJCMlsVKhJF@hMr9UydjNrNi7xqw4qDZRySU1sUjBPT/HzsZOCShSXVTn8f8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Çÿ╣á╕♠½ß¡U¶[k╔╒j⌂?6▓╓○÷⌂I╬&⌂Γ╚?╟A
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8098b9a0b806abe1ad55145b6bc9d56a7f3f36b2d609f67f49ce267fe2c83fc741&i=&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 49 bytes

Just a blatant port of the CJam answer.

```
"Happy Birthday to You
"...15<"Dear GolfScript
"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8kjsaCgUsEps6gkIyWxUqEkXyEyv5RLSU9Pz9DURsklNbFIwR2oPhisnkvJ4f9/AA)

Comment: A month earlier and this would have been a proper salutation to Golfscript

Comment: This is exactly what I had, though I hadn't seen the CJam answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 78 bytes

I have forgotten about Wren so I'm trying to use it.

```
Fn.new{(1..4).map{|i|"Happy Birthday "+(i==3?"Dear Wren":"to You")}.join("
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8WsNQT89EUy83saC6JrNGySOxoKBSwSmzqCQjJbFSQUlbI9PW1theySUVqDUcaIaSlVJJvkJkfqmSZq1eVn5mnoYSF5D5P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVQNkh15yYk6OhqbmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```scala
print("Happy Birthday to You\n"*4 patch(59,"dear Scala",6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQ/b@gKDOvREPJI7GgoFLBKbOoJCMlsVKhJF8hMr80Jk9Jy0ShILEkOUPD1FJHKSU1sUghGGSeko6Zpub/2v8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 39 bytes

```
”ŽØ¢© ”“€„ “«”€î”«U,,”ŽØ¢©¬Ž 05AB1E”,X,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPco3sPzzi06NBKBSD7UcOcR01rHjXMA3LmHFoNEmlac3gdkD60OlRHB0n1oTVH9yoYmDo6GboCRXUidP7/BwA)

```
”ŽØ¢© ”“€„ “«”€î”«  # push "Happy Birthday to You"
U                   # store top of stack in variable X
,,                  # output top of stack twice
”ŽØ¢©¬Ž 05AB1E”     # push "Happy Birthday Dear 05AB1E"
,                   # output top of stack
X,                  # output X
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Sandwich](https://tildegit.org/karx/sandwich), 64 bytes

```
lhHappy Birthday
lt$h to you
ld$h dear sandwich

p$t
p$t
p$d
p$t
```

---

Bit of a naive approach, but it works.

Explanation:
Sandwich is comprised of opcodes. The first letter of each line is the opcode, and the rest of the characters of the line are the arguments that are passed to the opcode.

Above code with comments:

```
lhHappy Birthday # Create variable h and assign "Happy Birthday"
lt$h to you # Create variable t and assign "$h to you", which resolves to Happy Birthday to you
ld$h dear sandwich # Create variable d and assign "$h dear sandwich", which resolves to Happy Birthday dear sandwich

p$t # print out variable t
p$t
p$d # print out variable d 
p$t
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 0):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 145 bytes

```
72/97Q/112/;/121N/32O/66/105/114P/116R/104T/100/q/n/oa[./]a\Br/111S/o/89/s/117/10b[./]a[./]b[./]a[./]b\68.101.q.p.o.66.p.q.110.99.t.10.a[./]b[./]
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyI3Mi85N1EvMTEyLzsvMTIxTi8zMk8vNjYvMTA1LzExNFAvMTE2Ui8xMDRULzEwMC9xL24vb2FbLi9dYVxcQnIvMTExUy9vLzg5L3MvMTE3LzEwYlsuL11hWy4vXWJbLi9dYVsuL11iXFw2OC4xMDEucS5wLm8uNjYucC5xLjExMC45OS50LjEwLmFbLi9dYlsuL10iLCIiLCIiXQ==)!

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 680 bytes

```
{i}ds{d}ic{ii}iiiiic{i}iiiiicc{i}dc{{d}i}ic{{i}ddd}ddddc{i}dddc{i}dciic{d}ddcddddcdddc{ii}iiiic{{d}i}ic{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{{i}d}dc{d}ciiiiiic{{d}d}iiic{iiiiii}iic{ii}iiiiic{i}iiiiicc{i}dc{{d}i}ic{{i}ddd}ddddc{i}dddc{i}dciic{d}ddcddddcdddc{ii}iiiic{{d}i}ic{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{{i}d}dc{d}ciiiiiic{{d}d}iiic{iiiiii}iic{ii}iiiiic{i}iiiiicc{i}dc{{d}i}ic{{i}ddd}ddddc{i}dddc{i}dciic{d}ddcddddcdddc{ii}iiiic{{d}i}ic{iiii}ddddc{iii}iiicddddc{ii}dddc{{d}ii}ddc{iiii}ddddc{iii}iiicddddciiiciiciiic{i}c{d}dc{ii}iic{{d}dd}iiiic{iiiiii}iic{ii}iiiiic{i}iiiiicc{i}dc{{d}i}ic{{i}ddd}ddddc{i}dddc{i}dciic{d}ddcddddcdddc{ii}iiiic{{d}i}ic{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{{i}d}dc{d}ciiiiiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VBbCoAwDDuRh5JGMd/7HD37NG0VEQ8gODZIm6SPYZmxsm3TGJ2O1uG0Tjp1DlRACNZFS6AI0IMlToEsSlswmc4SD2/mkAXEXJTawI28XCFWIR3n3@eLLuVM0s7Ib@MW/yoViBsTRstqlAvV@t/88jF2)

-18 thanks to @astonearachnid

Comment: -18 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VBbCoAwDDuRh5JGMd/7HD37NG0VEQ8gODZIm6SPYZmxsm3TGJ2O1uG0Tjp1DlRACNZFS6AI0IMlToEsSlswmc4SD2/mkAXEXJTawI28XCFWIR3n3@eLLuVM0s7Ib@MW/yoViBsTRstqlAvV@t/88jF2 "Deadfish~ – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 96 bytes

```typescript
type F<A=`
Happy Birthday `,//@ts-ignore
B=`${A}to You`>=`${B}${B}${A}dear TypeScript Types${B}`
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAQQLwAMBQAJAhmMIoBCAlgE7AAWAJlvigDQD0DAAsAM4C0RA5gHYD2JCGgKoAJAG8EAX2D8oATX4BXFAD5xEgtMnbJMyhCwkoAFXAQAygGMSRMMDMW2u6ejShIUAB5QksNCYoYIA9AH40IA)

Outputs with a leading newline.

Or, more elegantly but 3 bytes longer:

### [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 99 bytes

```typescript
type Z<S="to You">=`Happy Birthday ${S&string}
`
type F=`${Z}${Z}${Z<"Dear TypeScript Types">}${Z}`
```

[Try it at the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWgPAZQLwCJgHsoE10FcUB8SABgBICGYYIUAQgJYBOwAFgCbk0AkA3ggGQBnYI3oA7AOYBfAFDEZoSFABiJXjCnrNPeCgAiEcoygAVcBAQBjUWGCFtG+QHonUNwD0A-DKA)

Outputs with a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>37</s> 36 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
4Æ`Happy Bir »y {XÍ?`  Y `:`De  Japt
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=NMZgSGFwcHkgQmlykLt5IHtYzT9gkSBZjGA6YERlhyBKYXB0)

-1 byte, thanks to Shaggy

Oliver's solution is very clever, this one is 2 bytes shorter but requires the `R` flag.

#### Explanation

```
4Æ                 Map each X in [0,4) to:
  `Happy Bir »y {    "Happy Birthday " with the following appended:
     XÍ                take 2 - X
       ?`  Y `           nonzero -> "to You"
       :`De  Japt        zero -> "Dear Japt"
                   R flag: output the result joined by newlines.
```

Comment: [36 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=NMZgSGFwcHkgQmlykLt5IHtYzT9gkSBZjGA6YERlhyBKYXB0)

Comment: @Shaggy Nice! I forgot about that trick, goes to show how rusty I am

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Batch Scripting (88 bytes)

```
set "t=Happy Birthday to You"
set n=^&echo.
echo %t%%n%%t%%n%%t:to You=Dear Batch%%n%%t%
```

[image: happy_bday]

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 134 bytes

```
fn main(){let a=("Happy Birthday To you"," Dear Rust");for i in 1..3{println!("{}",a.0);}println!("{}{}",a.0,a.1);println!("{}",a.0);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
fn main(){
    let a = ("Happy Birthday To you", " Dear Rust");

for i in 1..3{
    println!("{}" ,a.0);
}

println!("{}{}" ,a.0, a.1);

println!("{}",a.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 68 bytes

```swift
let t="to You"
[t,t,"Dear Swift",t].map{print("Happy Birthday "+$0)}
```

If you love Swift enough to let it compile a program without any `unused result` warnings for once (I know I do), then for 70 bytes:

```swift
let t="to You"
_=[t,t,"Dear Swift",t].map{print("Happy Birthday "+$0)}
```

Answer (score -2):

## C# LinqPad, 103 bytes

```
Regex.Replace(String.Join("\n",Enumerable.Repeat("Happy Birthday to You",4)),"^((.*\n){2}.*)to.+","$1C#")
```