# Tips for golfing in The Shakespeare Programming Language

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in The Shakespeare Programming Language? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to SPL (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: I'm not certain that you _can_ golf SPL. SPL is so verbose that I almost feel like this question needs the code trolling tag. :P

Comment: You just can't golf SPL. At least, to my feeble knowledge of Shakesperian lore...

Comment: @RodolfoDias: Feeble? I think you're the resident Shakespeare scholar on PPCG.

Comment: @AlexA. Which may not be a good thing: it just means I'm demented enough to try and understand SPL :-)

Comment: @AlexA. Sp can do it...

Comment: This is not a golfing tip, but a note. On `Listen tothy!` command (aka `int_input`) it's undefined behavior if there are nothing left in the input, so you can't reliably determine EOF with integer input.

Answer (score 20):

(Well... since this is my *adopted* language <sup>1</sup>, I feel like I'm obliged to add something here)

### Use short variable names

Yeah, yeah, yeah, that's pretty standard to code-golf, you just use one-letter-length variable names, no news here. Or is there? Because the chaps that created SPL were wacky enough not to allow any name for their language's variables: they **must** come from Shakesperian plays which, in terms of character length, is a pain in the royal tush - but, if you're coding in SPL, you already know that. So, my advice would be to use characters with short names, like *Ajax*, *Ford*, *Page* or *Puck*, instead of *The Archbishop of Canterbury*, per instance.

That's all I got, I'm afraid.

---

<sup>1</sup>- since my Java skills are equivalent of those of a newborn.

Comment: [Variable name list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142011).

Answer (score 15):

## Any Roman numeral is a valid scene number

That means, that instead of:

```
Scene I
Scene II
Scene III
Scene IV
Scene V
```

You can do:

```
Scene L
Scene I
Scene C
Scene X
Scene V
```

Comment: is `D` a valid Roman numeral? IIRC, it's 500 (but I'm not sure if it's valid in SPL)

Comment: @Giuseppe I don't understand why you don't just check that, but the official SPL interpreter supports M, C, D, X, L, I and V.

Answer (score 14):

(after doing the previous one, I just remembered a few things)

### Choose your code carefully

An example, to try and explain what this mean.

```spl
Ajax:
 You are as warm as a big red rich fair cute bold cat!
```

and

```spl
Ajax:
 Thou art as blossoming as an embroidered trustworthy bottomless peaceful charming handsome chihuahua!
```

produce the exact same result, which is make the *character* being spoken to assume the value 64 (since, assuming you [read my long battle with SPL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44766/32139), you know that both lines are equivalent to 2*2*2*2*2*2*1); however, the first one has 59 bytes, while the second one has a bytecount of 107.

Still, no one is going to be demented enough to enter a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge with SPL, so...

Comment: Could you use the same adjective multiple times in a description?  E.g. `a big big big big big big cat`, saving 4 more bytes?  I know it ruins the artistry... but this is code golf after all.  ;)

Comment: @DLosc, from what I've seen, there's nothing forbidding you to do that. So... you're a better golfer than me ^_^

Comment: Ahem. Don't call Robert Fraser demented. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69360/43394

Answer (score 11):

## Remove unneeded words

Look at this (inserting newlines and whitespace for readability):

```
Puck:You is a big big cat!
     Open your heart!
Ajax:Be you worse than I?
     If so, let us return to Scene V!
     If not, you is a cat.
     You is the sum of I and the sum of a cat and you
     Speak thy mind!
     [Exeunt]
```

Looks pretty golfed eh? Here's an even more stripped down unintelligible form:

```
Puck:You big big cat!
     Open heart!
Ajax:Be you worse I?
     If solet usScene V!
     If notyou cat.
     You is the sum ofI the sum ofa cat you.
     Speak thy!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BCoMwDIbvPkW8Sx/Ay3Cwg6cNhIEMD10Xp9O1YlOmT981m0NXSAnJ9/ejdui9b0T2kFMiTk51icgUQZ6KQqFGbi4HTTgCIyD1DZiqIr7T0ji4tvdPKUlxBL9zHFBDg3JchpxO9whzSLzMaMPLu5XOa7CmRwJnv9pz/LfUhjgYFGKds7y1QA2CdU8wdb7pJcNs2wSKAWUXmDmOFgt/bkKnqfL@DQ)

For reference, here's a list of easily removable words from code:

- **Speak thy mind**  -> **Speak thy**
- **Open your heart** -> **Open heart** *****
- **Listen to thy heart** -> **Listen tothy**
- **Open your mind** -> **Open mind** *****
- **You is a cat**    -> **You cat** *****
- Only applies to constants such as `big cat`, otherwise you still need the 'is'
- **Let us return to**   -> **Let us**
- **Be X [op] than Y?**      -> **Be X [op] Y?**
- **You is [op] of X** -> **You is [op] ofX**
- **You is [op] of X and Y** -> **You is [op] ofX Y**
- **[Exeunt]**        -> (removed entirely)

Legend:

- `X` and `Y` are constants like `cat`, `I` or `you`
- `[op]` are operations like `nicer`, `the sum of`
- ***** means you can remove the punctuation if it's the last sentence of the play

If I come across any others I'll add it to the list.

For extra reference, here's the shortest header to start off a program:

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy@gNDkbSCampwJFkksUPK30gpNT81JBjGjXvJLUIgWQQoXEvBQFkNrY//8B)

Add Page and Ford as extra characters as necessary.

Comment: If you need even more characters, there's a list [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142011/55934)

Answer (score 10):

## Use short words

So here they are:

- Use `a` instead of `an` or `the`, except the expressions `the sum of` and similar, since they won't work with `a`.
- Use `am`, `be` or `is` instead of `are` or `art`.
- Use `I` instead of `me` or `myself`.
- Use `you` instead of `thee`, `thou`, `thyself` or `yourself`.
- Use `big` for adjectives.
- Use `cat` for positive numbers.
- Use `pig` for negative numbers.
- Use `zero` for zero.
- Use `worse` for `A < B` (instead of `smaller` or `punier`).
- Use `nicer` for `A > B` (instead of `better`, `bigger`, `fresher`, `friendlier` or `jollier`).
- Character names:

  - 4 letters: Ajax, Ford, Page, Puck
  - 5 letters: Egeus, Helen, Julia, Lucio, Mopsa, Paris, Pinch, Priam, Regan, Robin, Romeo, Timon, Titus, Venus, Viola
  - 6 letters: Adonis, Aegeon, Alonso, Angelo, Arthur, Banquo, Bianca, Brutus, Cicero, Dorcas, Duncan, Emilia, Fenton, Hamlet, Hecate, Hector, Helena, Hermia, Imogen, Juliet, Lennox, Oberon, Olivia, Orsino, Portia, Thaisa, Thurio, Tybalt
  - 7 letters: Adriana, Aemilia, Agrippa, Antonio, Capulet, Cassius, Claudio, Dionyza, Escalus, Goneril, Horatio, Leonato, Luciana, Macbeth, Macduff, Malcolm, Mariana, Miranda, Octavia, Ophelia, Orlando, Othello, Pantino, Proteus, Publius, Shallow, Shylock, Slender, Solinus, Theseus, Titania, Troilus, Ulysses
  - 8 letters: Achilles, Beatrice, Benedick, Benvolio, Claudius, Cordelia, Cressida, Dogberry, Don John, Falstaff, Gertrude, Hermonie, Isabella, Lysander, Mercutio, Montague, Pericles, Polonius, Pompeius, Prospero, Rosalind, Stephano
  - 9 letters: Agamemnon, Antiochus, Autolycus, Balthazar, Brabantio, Cassandra, Cleopatra, Cornelius, Demetrius, Desdemona, Donalbain, Don Pedro, Ferdinand, Francisca, Hippolyta, King John, King Lear, Lychorida, Sebastian, The Ghost, Valentine, Vincentio
  - 10 letters: Andromache, Cymberline, Fortinbras, Friar John, King Henry
  - 11 letters: Mark Antony
  - 12 letters: Doctor Caius, King Richard, Lady Capulet, Lady Macbeth, Lady Macduff, Prince Henry, Queen Elinor
  - 13 letters: John of Gaunt, Julius Caesar, Lady Montague, Mistress Ford, Mistress Page
  - 14 letters: Friar Laurence, The Apothecary
  - 15 letters: Christopher Sly, Octavius Caesar
  - 17 letters: John of Lancaster, Mistress Overdone, The Duke of Milan
  - 18 letters: The Duke of Venice
  - 24 letters: The Abbot of Westminster
  - 28 letters: The Archbishop of Canterbury
  - If you really need more, you definitely should consider using the stack of each character.

Comment: Note that multi-word characters can omit any spaces after their name (from [user202729's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165561/76162)), so they are preferable to characters with only one word

Answer (score 9):

## Use only one scene

Normally, you can't reuse the first scene of an act, since it always has `[Enter Ajax and Puck]` first thing. However, you can preface this with `[Exeunt]` to be able to reuse the first scene of a play. `[Exeunt]` is one byte shorter than declaring a new scene, and jumping to an Act is two bytes less than jumping to a Scene.

E.g: A simple cat program

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Page and Ajax]Scene V:.Ajax:Open mind!Speak thy!Let usScene V!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8gMT0VyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTGiXfNKUosUQJIKiXkpCiC1sRDZMCuwTiv/gtQ8hdzMvBTF4ILUxGyFkoxKRZ/UEoXSYqg6xf//E5OSAQ)

To:

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Page and Ajax]Ajax:Open mind!Speak thy!Let usAct I!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8gMT0VyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTGiXStSS/NKYqNd80pSixRAihQS81IUQHpiQYSVf0FqnkJuZl6KYnBBamK2QklGpaJPaolCaTHYLMX//xOTkgE)

Answer (score 7):

## You don't have to switch people in conditionals.

For example,

```
Ajax:Is you better than the sum of a fat fat fat fat cat and a fat cat?
Puck:If so,let us return to Scene I.
```

is longer than

```
Ajax:Is you better than the sum of a fat fat fat fat cat and a fat cat?If so,let us return to Scene I.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Jumps can be shorter

You can use `return to` even if the scene is ahead, and vice versa. In fact, the interpreter doesn't even care if you omit it entirely. This means these four statements are 100% equivalent:

```
Let us proceed to Scene X.
Let us return to Scene X.
Let us Scene X.
Let usScene X.
```

Comment: Jo King (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164394/76162) has found that "Let us Scene X" is enough.

Comment: @EdWynn good to know. I rewrote the answer to include this.

Comment: [`Let usscene X` is enough](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165561).

Answer (score 6):

## Remove redundant spaces

Apart from the trivial ones (two adjacent spaces, adjacent to a punctuation, adjacent to a newline, at the end) (with some exceptions), the space after the following tokens can be removed:

- `the sum of`
- `let us`
- `the ghost` ([like this](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8kI1XBPSO/uAQokFyi4GmlF5ycmpcKYkS75pWkFinAVSTmpSiANMVygUgrLoXI/FKF5MQSPS6FSiArsShVoQSotrg0VyE/DcRKB@mCM4DK/AtS8xQyUhOLSvT@/09MSgYA)) (but who would use this character anyway)
- `if so` and `if not` (remove the `,` after this, and don't need to add any space. Example: `if solet usact I`)
- `listen to` (so `listen tothy` works, [like this](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy@gNDkbSCampwJFkksUPK30gpNT81JBjGjXvJLUIgWQQoXEvBQFkNpYEM/KJ7O4JDVPoSS/JKNSL78AyMxITSwq@f/f0MgYAA))
- and basically any multi-word [tokens](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl/blob/master/makescanner.c#L110-L142).

Note: This does not work with the [Perl interpreter](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Lingua-Shakespeare/lib/Lingua/Shakespeare.pod). It's probably just an unintended effect caused by Flex's parsing behavior. The ["language standard"](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/) is not clear about that.

Comment: Time to back and edit some of my answers... Very nice find!

Comment: Is that a bug in the tokenizer, or is that behavior defined in the language?

Comment: @Cœur See update.

Answer (score 5):

The "let us return to scene X" can be used even if the character being spoken to is off stage. So instead of:

```
Puck:Am I as fat as the sum of a big big big big big big cat and a cat?
Ajax:If not,let us return to scene III.
[Exit Puck]
[Enter Page]
Ajax:You is a big big big big big big cat.
```

You can do:

```
Puck:Am I as fat as the sum of a big big big big big big cat and a cat?
[Exit Puck]
[Enter Page]
Ajax:If not,let us return to scene III.You is a big big big big big big cat.
```

Answer (score 5):

## `If (so|not)` does not have to immediately follow the comparison.

```
Am I as big as you?You big big big big big cat.If so, you is the sum of you and a big big cat.
```

Comment: In fact, the results of a comparison are stored as a flag and can be used repeatedly across scene transitions or across several `If so`s. This can be helpful in avoiding repeating comparisons!

Answer (score 4):

## Instead of substracting, add constants

```
You is the difference between I and a big cat.
```

is longer than

```
You is the sum of I and a big pig.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Use 'square', 'cube', 'product' and 'factorial'

The operations `the square of`, `the cube of`, `the factorial of` and `the product of` exist but are only mentioned in passing (if at all) in the documentation. They can save you bytes to define (large-ish) constants. For instance, to get the number 64,

```
a big big big big big big cat
```

is 5 bytes longer than

```
the cube ofa big big cat
```

Similarly, the shortest way of getting 49 is with \$49=7^2\$ i.e.

```
the square ofthe sum ofa big big big cat a pig
```

and you can get 24 as \$4!\$ i.e.

```
the factorial ofa big big cat
```

There can be situations where viewing a number as the product of two smaller existing constants can make `the product of` useful.

Finally, note that there is also `the square root of`and `the quotient between`. Both round down, as the only type in SPL is integers: a short way to get 200 is as \$200 = \lfloor \sqrt{8!} \rfloor\$:

```
the square root ofthe factorial ofa big big big cat
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use shorter words

Examples:

`Thy` and `thyself` are shorter than `your` and `yourself`.

`Is` is shorter than `are`.

and more...

Answer (score 3):

## Gotos aren't the only commands usable with `If (so|not)`

```
Am I as big as you?If so,you is the sum of you and a big big cat.If not,you is the sum of you and twice I.
```

Answer (score 3):

## All newlines are ignored

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Page,.Act:.Scene:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:You Puck.[Exeunt]
```

Answer (score 3):

## You don't need the ending `.` or `!`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8gMT0VyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTGiXfNKUosUQEoUEvNSFECqYkE8q8j8UoXkxJL//xOTkgE)

This can also be used before a `[`. (thanks jimmy23013)

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:You cat[Exeunt]
```

Examples:

- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:You cat`
- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Open mind[Exeunt]`

Doesn't work in:

- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:[Enter Ajax]` (right after `Scene {number}:`) (however [this](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8gMT0VyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTIqFKJd80pSixRAahQS81IUQMpiwVwrBf@C1DyFjNTEopL//w0B) works, I don't know why)
- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Listen to your heart` (and shorter variants)
- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Let us return to scene I` (and shorter variants)
- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Recall` (only after empty `Recall`, `Recall x` or `Recall@` etc. works)
- `,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Speak thy` (without `mind`)

Comment: This doesn't to work in some situations where you've already removed a word, such as `Speak thy` or `Let us Scene I`

Answer (score 3):

## Use ‘twice’ and the distributive property

Instead of:

```
You is the sum ofa big big big big cat a big big big cat.
```

Use:

```
You is twice twice twice the sum ofa big cat a cat.
```

This saves 2 bytes per `twice` since 2 uses of `big` is 8 bytes (counting spaces) and `twice` is only 6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `<` or `>` instead of `==`

Not applicable to every situation, but it's quite a bit shorter:

#### Puck == Ajax

```
Puck:Is I as bad as you?
```

#### Puck < Ajax or Puck > Ajax

```
Puck:Is I worse you?
Puck:Is I nicer you?
```

4 bytes shorter for both!