# Consecutive 1-Bits are Incremented

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Given a pattern (string or array format) of Bits :
`[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

The tasks is to replace any number of consecutive 1-Bits with an ascending number sequence starting at 1.

**Input**

- Pattern (can be received as an string or array) Example:

  - String: `1001011010110101001`
  - Array: `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`

**Output**

- Ascending number sequence (can be returned as an string or array) Example:

  - String: `1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 1`
  - Array: `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`

**Rules**

- *(only apply for strings)* Input wont contain spaces between `1` and `0`
- Assume Input `length > 0`
- *(only apply for strings)* Output is separated by space (use any other separator if you need as long as is not a number or a letter from the alphabet)

**Example:**

```
Given [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
Output [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Given 0110101111101011011111101011111111     
Output 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Given 11111111111101    
Output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 1
```

---

Winning criteria: Codegolf

Answer (score 20):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
γ€ƶ˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZHTWuObTs95///aAMdQzA0gJIGOjARMIwFAA)
or as a [Test Suit](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVhn8/9zmR01rjm07Ped/pdLh/Qq6dgqH9yvp/DcwNDQEYgMDEAMIuEAcQwgHTEPFYWIgJYZIwMAQAA)

**Explanation**

```
γ      # split input into groups of consecutive equal elements
 €ƶ    # multiply each number in each sublist by its 1-based index in the sublist
   ˜   # flatten
```

Comment: Oof, better than mine. I would've never thought of this.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with codegolf byte-counting rules (and googling only found [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/) which didn't come to a conclusion).  While your answer is 4 characters shouldn't it at least be 8 bytes (e.g., utf-16-be without BOM `03 B3 20 AC 01 B6 02 DC`) or 9 bytes (utf-8: `CE B3 E2 82 AC C6 B6 CB 9C`) or 10 bytes (e.g., UTF-16 including the 2 byte BOM) in any non-toy encoding?  (Yes, one *could* construct a toy 8-bit encoding similar to iso-8859 encodings with these 4 symbols represented as 1-byte, but that seems like cheating.)

Comment: @drjimbob Yes, good question. The code can actually be converted to a binary file using the [05AB1E code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md). For example, `γ€ƶ˜` would be represented as `04 80 8F 98`. The code page primarily exists to make writing code easier. To run this 4-byte file, you would need to run the interpreter with the `--osabie` flag.

Answer (score 19):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 15 bytes

```hs
scanl1$(*).succ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLboMwELzzFaMoB6g2CEiTtlLopVJvPfdAOFhgEquOQba59ONLlygv2mgl27s7M16P98J9Sa2HBjm2g6uE0ek8fIhi11fVoEzXe4c8AAoUKd2PhNKSEYQiOeeUTPt07dyr38RE6cpLpsgRVQaBla7XtwNmtKRHWtGanuiZXihlFsOzPzNml7vPhGt@W13/wx2FJ0rLCy@ZIk8zHoQybG7dcqoaCFNjjm/VfSq/R7hVsFi8ooFCnsNGOHl@fprfS8NMcMH31iCMOJPayWNRWttazN6F0rKGl867OJ4F3DuI7gNhZ5XxiFk@ZgFRR7xrZSRbttlgJ/1ba7w03g1FGRRsUZGM@2gWr@P59AHlT9VosXPDouq6Xw)

#### Explanation/Ungolfed

`scanl1` iterates from left over a list using a function which takes the last result and the current element generating a new list with the results, leaving empty lists and singletons "unmodified".

`(*).succ` is the equivalent of `\x y-> (x+1)*y`

Using that function together with `scanl1` only works because the increasing sequences (*1,2,3,..*) start with *1* and either have no preceding element (in which case it's the first element in the list which won't be "modified") or they have a leading *0*.

Answer (score 15):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5 4</s> 3 bytes

```
ṁ∫g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxkcdq9P///8fbaBjCIYGUNJAByYChrEA)

#### Explanation

```
ṁ∫g  -- full function, example input: [1,1,1,0,1]
  g  -- group: [[1,1],[0],[1]]
ṁ    -- map the following and concatenate result (example with [1,1,1])
 ∫   -- | cumulative sum: [1,2,3]
     -- : [1,2,3,0,1]
```

**Edit history**

<sup>-1 byte by using `scanl1` over `zipWith`</sup>

<sup>-1 byte by porting [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis?tab=profile)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167594/48198)</sup>

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
c=0
for i in input():c=c*i+i;print c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9nWgCstv0ghUyEzD4gKSks0NK2SbZO1MrUzrQuKMvNKFJL//4820DEEQwMoaaADEwHDWAA)

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⊥⍨¨,\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXUsf9a44tEIn5v9/AwVDBSMFEAlhGSuYKJgi8ZFFzTDUmSmYK1g86lyYBhY1hMvDIIKPLIqpDgy50MxVsFQwBCoCyoCdAbbGEAcEygMA)

#### How it works

```apl
⊥⍨¨,\
   ,\  ⍝ Convert to lists of first n elements
⊥⍨¨    ⍝ Map "Count trailing ones" to each list
```

Comment: Nice usage of  the `⊥⍨` trick.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

Takes input as an array.

```javascript
a=>a.map(s=n=>s=n*-~s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQKPYNs/WDkho6dYVa/5Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI04g20DEEQwMoaaADEwHDWE29rPzMPA11HXVNTS6seg3gug3R@CgmYagjbL6hDnZogKbvPwA)

The shorter `a=>a.map(n=>a=n*-~a)` (20 bytes) would unfortunately fail on `[1]` because of coercion of singleton arrays to the integer they're holding.

Answer (score 11):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
#.~\
```

A port of Bubbler's APL solution

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9Zry7mvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkIaUJUhGBpASQO4CBiiKjOAKzRE46NowlAHgTCzDHFAkA6F/wA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
i.&0@|.\
```

### How?

It's simply the distance to the preceding `0`

```
       \  for each prefix
     |.   reverse it
    @     and
i.&0      find the index of the first 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D9TT83AoUYv5r8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr5CGlClIRgaQEkDuAgYoiozgCs0ROOjaMJQB4EwswxxQJAOhf8A)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer</sup>

```python
i=1
for x in input():i*=x;print i;i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWkCstv0ihQiEzD4gKSks0NK0ytWwrrAuKMvNKFDKtM7VtDf//jzbQMQRDAyhpoAMTAcNYBQA)

Comment: I don't think you need the `,`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it looks prettier this way c:

Comment: Sorry, but sometimes, in life, you have to make sacrifices.

Comment: RIP `,` you're not in the code anymore, but you will be forever in my heart

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
‘×¥\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4zD0w8tjfn//3@0gY4hGBpASQMdmAgYxgIA)

```
‘×¥\
   \   Accumulate the input with:
  ¥   The dyad
‘      Increment the left element
 ×    Multiply by the second element (1 or 0)
       The result always begins with the first element unchanged
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 31 bytes

```r
function(a)sequence(rle(a)$l)*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq6DwP600L7kkMz9PI1GzOLWwNDUvOVWjKCcVyFXJ0dRK/J@mkaxhoGMIhgZQ0kAHJgKGmpr/AQ)

`sequence`, which ["mainly exists in reverence to the very early history of R"](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sequence.html), is quite handy here.

```r
function(a)                       # function, taking a vector as argument
                    rle(a)$l      # take the lengths of the run-length encoding
           sequence(        )     # and generate the list [1:x for x in lengths]
                             *a   # multiply by a to maintain 0s, and return
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ŒgÄF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPTDLW7/H@7eEvaoaQ0QHW4HEu7//xsYGhoCsYEBiAEEXCCOIYQDpqHiMDGQEkMkYGAIAA)

#### How it works

```
ŒgÄF  Main link. Argument: A (bit array)

Œg    Group adjacent, identical bits.
  Ä   Accumulate; take the cumulative sum of each chunk.
   F  Flatten.
```

Comment: With the group runs quick Erik had suggested this would be three bytes! (If I understood what it would do correctly)

Comment: @dylnan The problem is that it's hard to decide on a behavior for such a quick. :( That's why the quick is still in hiatus.

Comment: There could be multiple quicks for the main possible implementations

Answer (score 6):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{y*1+x}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7pSy1C7ojbGQMEQCA2gGAYRfGRRTHVg@P8/AA)

**Explanation:**

Iterate over the list. Increment accumulator, multiply by current item (which resets accumulator if item is 0):

```
{y*1+x}\ / the solution
{     }\ / iterate (\) over lambda function
     x   / accumulator
   1+    / add 1
 y*      / multiply by current item
```

Answer (score 5):

## RAD, 8 bytes

```
(⊢×1+⊣)⍂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pM@f9f41HXosPTDbUfdS3WfNTb9P//f0MFQwUDBUMA)

### How?

- `(⊢×1+⊣)`, if the right argument is `0`, return `0`, otherwise increment the left argument
- `⍂`, LTR Scan (`(A f B) f C` instead of `A f (B f C)`) , apply this across the array

Answer (score 5):

## [TIS](https://github.com/Phlarx/tis), 68 + 33 = 101 bytes

Code (68 bytes):

```
@0
MOV UP ACC
SUB 47
MOV ACC ANY
@1
ADD 1
JRO UP
SUB ACC
MOV ACC ANY
```

Layout (33 bytes):

```
2 1 CC I0 ASCII - O0 NUMERIC - 32
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCoAgFATQ/T/FXEDwW9A20xYGZhQGHSFoV/f/WStnNzPvOW@RXlNMO/IC6xxteUDb/UupsPNBPZP1HkzTmgr7yUcrI8JVNIu6xIBR3qBhNxcCFJLGnOO4BldKY14)

Explanation:

```
|    Input 0    |    Input is given in ASCII (`0` is 48, `1` is 49)
+--------+------+
| Node 0 |      |    This node prepares the input data
+--------+      |
| MOV UP ACC    |    Read in a character
| SUB 47        |    Subtract 47 to map [48, 49] to [1, 2]
| MOV ACC ANY   |    Send the 1 or 2 to the next node
|               |    Implicitly wrap back to top of node
+--------+------+
| Node 1 |      |    This node does the incrementing/printing
+--------+      |
| ADD 1         |    Increment counter (starts at zero)
| JRO UP        |    Get value from above, and jump forward that many lines  (skip next line or not)
| SUB ACC       |    Reset counter to zero (if input was zero)
| MOV ACC ANY   |    Send the counter value downward to be printed
|               |    Implicitly wrap back to top of node
+---------------+
|   Output 0    |    Output is space-delimited numeric values
```

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 38 bytes

```c
f(a,i)int*a;{while(--i)*++a*=-~a[-1];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUxLCoMwFNz3FI@UQmKSYpaSehKbRYhaH9go1tKFpFdPn9IZBgbmE/QjhHzGGMZ32wF7rS1O14HlnnuFAuNaeLt9Bhw7rjWKQkpf1PrrG22cTfnpMXKxnYBAZfCNgxo2o4wqieYQMdmjsr9W4u@nhe8TrEsLeKssSIniiHbMC4U9Z5f2HpmiY3Q0TPkH)

Save one byte thanks to Toby Speight!

Save 6 bytes by using *= and a smarter while condition.

Comment: You can save 1 byte: `*(a-1)` → `a[-1]`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>29 24</s> 18 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Sean!*

```perl6
*.map:{($+=1)*=$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0svN7HAqlpDRdvWUFPLViW@9r81V3FipUKaRrSBjiEYGkBJAx2YCBjGasJVwlQhyxsg6TTEKo5q1n8A)

The inner function could by `($+=1)*=*`, but then the anonymous variable would persist across function calls. We get by this by wrapping it in an explicit code block.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*.map:               # Map the array to
      {($+=1)    }   # The anonymous variable incremented
             *=$_    # Multiplied by the element
```

Comment: I got the same basic approach down to 16 bytes: `*.map(($+=1)*=*)`.  This solution has the proviso that the state variable `$` persists across calls to the function, so if the final element passed to one call and the first element passed to the next call are both nonzero, then the counting will start with the wrong number.

Comment: @Sean, Yeah I remember struggling with that when I originally answered. Fortunately I've learned a way around that since then

Comment: You can knock one more byte off: `*.map:{...}`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ṛȧ+ɗ\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztknlmufnB7z////aAMdQzA0gJIGOjARMIwFAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes

```hs
scanl1$((*)=<<).(+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvzg5MS/HUEVDQ0vT1sZGU09DW/N/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkK0gY4hGBpASQMdmAgYxv7/l5yWk5he/F83wjkgAAA)

**Explanation:**
The code is equivalent to `scanl1(\b a->(b+a)*a)`, where `b` is the current bit and `a` is the accumulator. `scanl1` takes a list, instantiates the first list element as accumulator, and folds over the list and collects the intermediate values in a new list.

*Edit: [BMO beat me by a few seconds and 4 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167588/56433).*

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
åÏ*°X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5c8qsFg=&input=WzAsMSwxLDEsMCwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDFdCi1R)

---

### Explanation

```
åÏ        :Cumulatively reduce
   °X     :  Increment the current total (initially 0)
  *       :  Multiply by the current element
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>55</s> 48 bytes

```java
a->{int p=0,i=0;for(int v:a)a[i++]=v<1?p=0:++p;}
```

Modifies the input-array instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

-7 bytes thanks to *@TimSeguine*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVFNb4MwDL3vV/iYChqFaxmb9gPWS49VD16aTqE0oMQwVYjfztwAk7ovOYlkx@8956XEDtfl8TzqCkOAV7SufwCwjow/oTawvaUAXW2PoAXX9wfAVc7FgTevQEhWwxYcFDDi@qnnJmgKldpC5afa30DQbXCFe5skh6J7zJ75epMkTT6M@cTStG8Vs8xkUe3Cs4gdeeveo@Y0CJlAwpkPiKP0Ks1iqPlU6VKJMcRJ/0CpL1z2Lb/j@NH3H3OW/h5qQdy7Fh8aKRZnp1c6qQXOCrtrIHORdUuyYTOocqLkX5Mt2Uq@eI/XIKmejGLQrDKMnw)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{             // Method with integer-array parameter and no return-type
  int p=0,       //  Previous integer, starting at 0
      i=0;       //  Index-integer, starting at 0
  for(int v:a)   //  Loop over the values of the input-array:
    a[i++]=v<1?  //   If the current value is 0:
          p=0    //    Reset the previous integer to 0
         :       //   Else:
          ++p;}  //    Increase `p` by 1 first with `++p`
                 //    and set the current item to this new value of `p`
```

Comment: You can shave it down to 48: `a->{int p=0,i=0;for(int b:a)a[i++]=b<1?p=0:++p;}`

Comment: @TimSeguine Thanks! Now that I see it I can't believe I hadn't thought about it myself.

Comment: I was able to get rid of p, but it is the same size :( `a->{int i=0;for(int v:a)a[i]+=v*i++<1?0:a[i-2];}`

Answer (score 4):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 5 bytes

```
ẋ+⊣¦_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@Gubu1HXYsPLYv/n/qobeL/aAMFQzA0gJIGCjARMIwFAA)

#### Explanation

```
ẋ+⊣¦_     Full program
ẋ         Split into chunks of equal adjacent values.
   ¦_     And for each chunk, flattening the result afterwards...
 +⊣       Reduce it cumulatively on + (addition); aka cumulative sums
```

<sub>Ugh, I thought SE code fonts were monospace....</sub>

Comment: They are monospace... There is a space missing on the first line.

Comment: Look at the edit. It is still misaligned.

Comment: You must be looking from a mobile device or something - It looks fine to me

Comment: @micsthepick [I'm not...](https://imgur.com/a/FMO46Yc)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
FoldList[+###2&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98tPyfFJ7O4JFpbWVnZSC32f0BRZl5JtLKCrp1CWrRybKyCmoK@g0J1taGOggEYGcJIQ7xcqOJaHYVquDyaWgMkLgKh6ECzwBCvxfjVYLPHEJckmjG1tf8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>48</del> <del>40</del> 25 bytes

<sup>Thanks Mazzy for -8</sup>
<sup>Thanks AdmBorkBork for -15</sup>

```powershell
$args[0]|%{($i=$_*=++$i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iC2RrVaQyXTViVey1ZbWyVTs/b///8OGgY6hmBoACUNdGAiYKgJAA)

Takes input as an array numbers. Uses the self-assigning, multiply trick other answers are using and updates everything with a very gross assignment. It then wraps this whole thing in parens to push it to output.

Comment: Given: 'Output ... can be returned as an string **or array**' ) I think `param($p)$a=@();$p|%{$a+=$i=$_*=++$i};$a` is enough. 40 bytes

Comment: 25 bytes by using `$args[0]` and getting rid of `$a` -- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iC2RrVaQyXTViVey1ZbWyVTs/b///8OGgY6hmBoACUNdGAiYKgJAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

### Shakespeare, 365 bytes

```
I.Ajax,.Ford,.Act I:.Scene I:.[enter Ajax and Ford]Ajax:Open mind!Scene V:.Ford:Am I nicer than the sum of a big red old cute hard cat a big red old cute joy?Ford:If so,you is the sum of thyself a son!Ford:If not,you is zero!Ford:Open heart!Ajax:you is a big red old cute hard cat.Ajax:Speak mind!Ajax:Open mind!Ford:Am I nicer than zero?Ajax:If so, let us Scene V.
```

[try it here](https://tio.run/##fZA/a8MwEMW/yvNuRLJqCV4KnjoEupQMqnWpndp3RpKhzpd39CcppYRKIJ1OPz29Oz@P29aq5mK@a/Uiztaq6QJarY4dMaXgnTiQQ0Jg2CJRp3TSrzMxpoFtVeA3nSV0M6EFD118FXrDcSH4ZYKcYfAxfMKRhYwW3RIIvXExMuHZ3UXWQ5Zsz/BSr7Jg8L/1Qr96GpOuF64eKEt4sFdyUvLZbU/GhSq7vwP/OMpt0ceZzFcp80/VT4tNHx4yWDxjpIDF494itW27/X4XZxp5L@FPLo4b)

### less golfed version

```
I.Ajax,.Ford,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[enter Ajax and Ford]
Ajax:Open mind!
Scene V:.
Ford:Am I nicer than the sum of a big red old cute hard cat a big red old cute joy?     <- smallest way to 48 (ascii "0") I could think of
Ford:If so,you is the sum of thyself a son!
Ford:If not,you is zero!
Ford:Open heart!
Ajax:you is a big red old cute hard cat.    <- get value of 32 or space
Ajax:Speak mind!                            <- then output it
Ajax:Open mind!
Ford:Am I nicer than zero?
Ajax:If so, let us Scene V.                 <- loop through inputs
```

Comment: [280 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZBBbwIhEIX/ynA3G73updHEJps06cGTMR6QfSrt7rCFIWr//JbBtIcOITPA9x4DaRrmuWvWH/a@aF5D7BfN2gl1bbNzYGhx2N6RWY6HLQsiKUqWe1L6qKv2fQLT6Lk3G9AjZLqFmEDfiOGlO1MKEc4Og1FFWxC5giJGWxTFMJzrxlcO4sFCJ8gN4I4snfyFnBVi7wr468dB9JLJX8y@ZJ@qPuWxWOmBVY2pTV1ho5japKLq938qu5tgP58veINQTvUPzDwvV6tlGRo1P8u/vRI/). Check out the [SPL tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/tips-for-golfing-in-the-shakespeare-programming-language) for golfing tips.

Answer (score 4):

## C++, 47 bytes

```cpp
[](int*a,int*b){for(int c=0;a!=b;)c=*a++*=1+c;}
```

A lambda that modifies an array in place, given start and end pointers.

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDbioQwDH3vV2RdWKy64Lx6@4p5m5mHWOtQ0FZqHBjEb3erVVh2EwjNSZpzEjEM308h1pGQlACcyIAweiRooYT19giVpgiTLdZ8bo3dABBlmuNHWedclBHGcVReYpEva84Y@1RadFMjC2VGshL76hdE0iIZWzFGsh86JFnQe5AaewnXih0yXkY1MFjHFHox1y9Aa/HN2czAmdMB4S72hd0ks7MKh43UZJkwE0FR@JbtEUCQs3/l4K4dvDC2Ldaj0uHJsgF0e7hDzGly2T09YpqcyO6Ln@slE/dZG@48tXy6mcQTTyt14xL@98Oy/gA) (requires Javascript)

---

Generic version at 55 bytes (this works for any container with elements of arithmetic type):

```cpp
[](auto a,auto b){for(auto c=*a-*a;a!=b;)c=*a++*=1+c;};
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
ḅ{a₀ᵇ+ᵐ}ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO1urER00ND7e2az/cOqEWiJP//4820DHQMcQBDaAkmppYhf9RAA)

*(-2 bytes thanks to @Fatalize.)*

```
ḅ             % split input into "blocks" of equal value
 {     }ᵐ     % map this predicate on each such block:
  a₀ᵇ            % Find all prefixes (initial subsequences) of the block
                 %  Returns them in increasing order of length
     +ᵐ          % Sum the values in each subsequence
                 % This results in each block being replaced by its cumulative sum values
         c    % concatenate the results back into a single array
```

`~c{≤₁a₀ᵇ+ᵐ}ᵐc` is temptingly just out of reach at 13 bytes, but I haven't been able to find a shorter way of doing cumulative sum than the 5 byte `a₀ᵇ+ᵐ`.

Comment: `ḅ{+ℕ₁⟦₁|}ᵐc` is 1 byte shorter

Comment: `ḅ{a₀ᵇ+ᵐ}ᵐc` is 2 bytes shorter and should work, right?

Comment: @Fatalize Yep. I was an idiot, I even mentioned the cumulative sum idea for the alternate solution, but didn't apply it to this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 6 bytes

```
m=Z*hZ
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%3DZ%2ahZ&input=%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D+&debug=0)

#### How it works

```
m=Z*hZ – Full program. Q = the evaluated input.
m      – For each integer d in Q.
 =Z    – Assign the variable Z (preinitialised to 0) to...
   *hZ – (Z + 1) * d; (d is implicit at the end).
```

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to get an answer in using regular expressions.  There is probably an easier solution which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 86 bytes

```powershell
Filter F{($_-split"(0)(\B|\b)"|?{$_-ne''}|%{$_-replace'(1+)',(1..$_.Length)})-join' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVNdS8MwFH3efsWldCRhS0k6PzeGolAU9MmBDyqjlugqXVubDJG2v70mXde54UMNpL099@Sce8tNmnyJTC5FFNEgyUTlreNAhUkMcyEVJv2837OVDiXM4BKTafs5nMHTw7dUYuXM12kkXiaT60z4SmCLWyO9u3GZ5rKOXP5rsdoEXBjDERzDCZzCGZwDZ8A5cBf0u6sqY1qNtw/WSDOjUW/3j4j9w2GrzluXXbxZ5iccGG362jfedXvIq/vvXk5dBWMH5uPWiu2L18KtdAED0GPRs6W/0sp6MOyFc6ud@NSgfiz1SO1Qt0YzodZZbNDmVAGeSZhcKO99FSxNsqFR8QmNkCE9ZqES9CaRCrDV0imFnJWwOSIB5bxEFn3bOoy2agTKfll5YaR0WV6O7QWVaRQqCzOCn6@K51diFRe5hmOBUFkMTJiJNPIDgTAfEjTC3HF0O3cifldLUhL6kYQxAlRW5ppUPw)

Answer (score 3):

## C (gcc), <s>57</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```
f(a,l,c,i)int*a;{for(c=i=0;i<l;)a[i++]=c=a[i]*-~c;}
```

Port of [Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167576/79343), modifies the array in-place. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##XU5BCoMwEDzrK4JQMCbSeI55iXgIQe2CjSW1h1bSr6cbmxZaWDazk5lhTD0ZE8JYaj5zw4GCXSstt3FxpVGghIR2llR3wFivjELQV/XTSB9QSc4abEnJlmfx0s7pe9cTRbaGE7FP89nf@SPF747Ay3fePNhpPWHcFR7Dgh1jPj2mCxUUhYnmSb1TWD76Aa1C4tOmT8SM7XWzi0PFWBYHIAVPzaGPbp9nblhvzqI39@EF).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say this is K&R C?

Comment: Possibly, but that would be true of a lot of answers. I'm no expert, but it's entirely possible it's not even valid K&R C. The thing is, we don't really care about the language standards on this site. If gcc allows you to mix K&R C with more modern stuff, then it's valid C for the purposes of golfing because gcc will compile it. See also: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c

Comment: I didn't realize until searching just now that C11 still supports the old identifier list function syntax, so nevermind. But your point holds regardless.

Comment: Suggest `f(a,l,c)int*a;{for(c=0;l--;)c=*a++*=c+1;}`

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 60 bytes

```
INPUT s$
FOR i=1TO LEN(s$)
b=MID$(s$,i)>="1
v=-b*v-b
?v
NEXT
```

Takes the input as a string; gives the output as numbers separated by newlines.

#### Explanation

We read the string `s$` and loop `i` from `1` up to its length.

`MID$(s$,i)` gets the substring from character `i` (1-indexed) to the end of the string. If this starts with a `1`, it will be lexicographically `>=` the string `"1"`; if it starts with a `0`, it will not be. So `b` gets `0` if the character at index `i` is `0`, or `-1` if the character is `1`.

Next, we update the current value `v`. If we just read a `0`, we want `v` to become `0`; otherwise, we want to increment `v` by one. In other words, `v = (-b) * (v+1)`; simplifying the math gives the shorter expression seen in the code. Finally, we print `v` and loop.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 60 bytes

```
([]){{}<>(())<>{{}<>({}({}))(<>)}{}([])}{}<>{({}[()]<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6VrO6utbGTkNDU9PGDsKsrgUiTU0NGzvNWiAbqKQWJF4NFI3W0IwFCtvYAfn//xsoGAKhARTDIIKPLIqpDgwB)

## Explanation:

```
([]){  For each element in the input
    {}
    <>(())<>  Push a one to the other stack
    { If the element is one,
       {}<>({}({}))(<>)  Add the one to a copy of the previous number in the series
    }{}  Pop the element
([])}  End loop
{}<>   Pop extra zero
{({}[()]<>)<>}<>   And reverse the output stack, subtracting one from each element
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 14 bytes

```
rv`0|(1)+
$#1¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v6gswaBGw1BTm0tF2fDQtv//DQwNDQwNDICUIZgFIhBsCAAA)

Answer (score 3):

### Java,  65 bytes

`void a(int[]q){for(int i=1;i<q.length;i++)q[i]+=q[i]>0?q[i-1]:0;}`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s>  10 bytes

```
0w"@+@*t]x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36BcyUHbQasktuL//2gDHUMwNICSBjowETCMBQA)

*(-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe)*

The obvious "accumulate y(x+y) over the array" approach.

#### 16 bytes

```
n:G~f!-tO<YYw(X<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8/KvS5NUbfE3yYyslwjwub//2gDHUMwNICSBjowETCMBQA)

Longer, more matrix-y approach: get the overall index, broadcast-subtract the indices of all zeros, and take the difference from the index of the nearest zero.

Comment: Do you need `D`? I removed it and it seems to work fine without it.

Comment: I had 12 bytes porting my R answer with `4#Y'"@:v!]G*`

Comment: Indeed I don't, the values will just accumulate in the stack in order. Thanks! (And your R answer's RLE approach is what I too started with, but soon got confused and lost. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
Ġv¦f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoHbCpmYiLCIiLCJbMCwxLDEsMSwwLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMV0iXQ==)

-6 thanks to Lyxal.

```
Ġ    # Group consecutive identical elements
 v¦  # Take the cumulative sum of each
   f # Flatten the result
```

Comment: [there is](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoHbCpmYiLCIiLCJbMCwxLDEsMSwwLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMV0iXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

### [Zig](https://github.com/ziglang/zig), 65 bytes

```
fn f(b:[]u8)[]u8{for(b)|_,i|{if(i>0)b[i]+=b[i-1]*b[i];}return b;}
```

Expanded version

```
fn f(b:[]u8) []u8 {
    // Foreach loop where only index is used.
    for(b) |_,i| {
        // First value is always going to be 0 or 1,
        if(i > 0)
            // b[1] will either be 0 or 1,
            // so this is basically an if statement
            // that we can use to reset the count.
            b[i] += b[i-1] * b[i];
    }
    return b;
 }
```

I would add a *Try it online!*, but their compiler seems to lack some crucial language features. (Language still being in development and all that)
And I am not going to attempt to make it compatible through trial and error.

But you can copy paste this into [Zig playground](https://zig-play.dev/) (Confirmed to work as of writing this post)

```
const std = @import("std");

fn f(b:[]u8)[]u8{for(b)|_,i|{if(i>0)b[i]+=b[i-1]*b[i];}return b;}

pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    var bits = [_]u8{0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    var array = f(bits[0..]);

    try std.io.getStdOut().writer().print("{any}\n", .{array});
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
zy.z(S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLqir1qjSCIRyo2IKbitEGOoZgaAAlDXRgImAYC1EJAA)

##### Explanation

```python
zy      # Group by consecutive
  .     # Apply to each:
   z(   #  Cumulative sums
     S  # Flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
(*/+\|,)\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxljEsKgDAMRPc5xZBNWxVt/FTt3hu4dN1TiGe3rSBFJ5BMHsMEr6uuPs7GHES7b5XSbEVsnKR8H/uyKCYALIWssKHNawtBj7QfN2DEVPwldb+cw4wldX8QVkjMCSQ3GKLtCmqnG8uDITk=)

-2 bytes thanks to ovs

Comment: Shorter with a lambda but tacit is fun.

Comment: Isn't `1+\/` just `+\ `?

Comment: That seems to hang for me.  I that turns it into converge on sum scan which is monadic.

Comment: [`(*/+\|,)\ `](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxljEsKgDAMRPc5xZBNWxVt/FTt3hu4dN1TiGe3rSBFJ5BMHsMEr6uuPs7GHES7b5XSbEVsnKR8H/uyKCYALIWssKHNawtBj7QfN2DEVPwldb+cw4wldX8QVkjMCSQ3GKLtCmqnG8uDITk=)

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I misread what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒgJ€F×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opHSvR01r3A5P////f7SBjiEYGkBJAx2YCBjGAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 15 bytes

```
.(?<=(1*))
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT8PexlbDUEtTk0tFz1Dh/39DAwNDA0NDOAHkcgGZYK4BiAEEClwwFYZwlQg2BHAZIgEDQwA) Link includes test cases. Alternative version, also 15 bytes:

```
.(?<=(1)*)
$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT8PexlbDUFNLk0tF2VDh/39DAwNDA0NDOAHkcgGZYK4BiAEEClwwFYZwlQg2BHAZIgEDQwA) Link includes test cases Explanation:

```
.
```

Match the 0s and 1s.

```
(?<=(1*))
(?<=(1)*)
```

Count the number of 1s from the current digit backwards. The first one counts by capturing the run of 1s as a subtring, while the second one counts the number of times the 1 was captured.

```
$.1 
$#1
```

Replace the digit with the number of 1s, either via the length of the capture or by the number of captures as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
t.u*YhNQZ
```

[Verify all the test cases](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Q%0At.u%2AYhNQZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%5D&debug=0)

```
t.u*YhNQZ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())

 .u    QZ   Cumulative reduce over Q, starting value 0
     hN       Increment the current value
   *Y         Multiply by the next value
t           Remove 1st element of list, implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## racket, 107 bytes

```
(λ(i)(let c((x i)(z 0))(if(empty? x)'()(if(= (car x)1)(cons(+ 1 z)(c(cdr x)(+ 1 z)))(cons 0(c(cdr x)0))))))
```

Comment: Possible space save in `= (`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 78 bytes

```
(<>)<>([]){{}{{}<>(({})())<>}([]){{}(<>)<>}{}([])}{}<>([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X8PGTtPGTiM6VrO6uhaIgGyN6lpNDU2gaC1UGKKmthrMrwWrgUqA2FDtQFZ17f//BgqGQGgAxTCI4COLYqoDQwA)

Readable version:

```
(<>)<>
([])

{

    {}

    {
        {}<>(({})())<>
    }

    ([])
    {

        {}(<>)<>
    }

    {}

    ([])

}{}<>

([])

{
    {}({}<>)<>([])
}<>{}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>52</strike> 51 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for the suggestion.

```c
c;f(char*i){for(;*i;printf("%d ",c=~c*(48-*i++)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCoMwEEX3nmKwFDJRi4EuCmm9SOlCRqMDNZZU3Yi9eppY6J/Ff8yDT0VH5A9s6Tk3LVzfU8Pjqa88aSOor51kXM3ohJasX47tZER6bCDN6fYhKc6XQnKWIaLefLAw1GxFhNp1lMcFkDLwgrAmAGxEFJVC2Gm5qwfqJBjXTrOzUOpk875UqgwXs/cP/7@QLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
t->(x=0;[(x=(x+y)y)for y=t])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@mYPu/RNdOo8LWwDoaSGpUaFdqVmqm5RcpVNqWxGr@z00s0Cgoyswrycl71DEjTUdBI9pAxxAMDaCkgQ5MBAxjdTQ1Ff4DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 41 bytes

Generic lambda, any int [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

```cpp
[](auto&a){int p=0;for(int&i:a)p=i*=p+i;}
```

Saved a byte with the `*=` operator, saved 4 bytes by removing unneeded braces and parenthesis.

Note: The `p+i` part can be replaced with `p+1` or `++p`, I'm not sure why I did `p+i` but it wouldn't save any bytes to change it.

Old:

```cpp
[](auto&a){int p=0;for(int&i:a){p=i=i*(p+i);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 22 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0map&=>[<=&*<=1+]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?RC2677)

```
$=>[        ; a function, assign input to &
    0       ; push 0
    map&=>[ ; map over input, assign current elt to &
        1+  ; increment tos
        <=  ; dup
        &*  ; multiply by current elt
        <=  ; dup
    ]       ; end map
]           ; end function
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 25 bytes

```
Prompt B
For(I,1,dim(⁻B
⁻B(I)(Ans+1
Disp Ans
End
```

Input is taken as a list. Output is as numbers separated by newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes (5 nibbles)

```
=\$+*
```

```
=\$+*       # full function
=\$+*$@$    # (with implicit arguments shown):
=\          # scan from left over
  $         # input
            # with function:
   +        #   add
       $    #   each element 
            #   to
    *       #   product of 
     $      #   each element
            #   and
      @     #   result so far
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 6 bytes

```
(×+⊢)`
```

[Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKMOXK+KKoilgCgpGIOKfqDAsMSwxLDEsMCwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDHin6k=)

#### Explanation

Port of [Dominic van Essen's Nibbles answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258990/16766).

```
(×+⊢)`
(    )`  Left scan on this function:
  +       Add
   ⊢      each element to
 ×        the product of the element and the previous intermediate value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [KamilaLisp v0.2](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 14 (APL SBCS)

```
$(⍀.←[+ * #1])
```

Equivalent to `$(scanl1[+ * #1])`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġıż×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhYrjiw8svHonsPTlxQnJRdDBRfcVIw20DEEQwMoaaADEwHDWIhKAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ġıż×  # Implicit input
ġ     # Group consecutive items
 ı    # Map over this list of lists:
  ż   #  Push [1..length] without popping
   ×  #  Multiply the two lists elementwise
      # Implicit output, summed (flattened)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>52</s> 46 bytes

```
f=lambda x,y=1:x and[y*x[0]]+f(x[1:],y*x[0]+1)
```

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Jo King and Rod!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @DomHastings*

```perl
s/./$i=$&*++$i.$"/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09fJdNWRU1LW1slU09FST899f9/A0NDAyAEATANYcLFgOBffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9oPh/3QIA)

**Method:**

Replace each character with itself multiplied by the incremented value of `$i`, then store that value back in `$i`.  Thus, `$i` starts at 0 (`undef`) and gets reset to 0 every time the character in the bit string is a 0.

Finally, append a space to the result of the above step to make the output format correct.

Comment: Nice again! You can save 2 bytes by dropping the `(` `)` as the trailing space is just ignored!

Comment: @Abigail In some languages, that may be the case, but in Perl, `++` has a higher precedence than either `=` or `*` and will always execute first.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 75 bytes

---

**Golfed** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFNS8QwEIbv@RVDEUlot6R6M20vC4JSEPTgYd1DqOnugKTSpHgo@e01Xdu1hd3V4YUZ5uOZMCnNqjTY37e6TB@0vb3ZbCMYgxwqyHqZ5V1VNxS1BcwSgamMC6V3di8wDBlWVG5wlWxzfu0D79jgsp9kmIhG2bbRIIUTfYHGpkc6AW9WGbuWRhnIQKsvWLRQBt2ha7ChOhagAx5BMonPAh4tSqPARX9x@BKVnMmfgJ@f/f/2y@IziBOE@P9QstzTI2m6IqCeXXS63rrWpv5Q8WuDVhWoFYWrwM9@tvYOug66F9ug3sWPNWoaROA1QZgD5970U2svNFf09wFsnAiACeIImXY/K/l@WM1E/w0)

```cs
a=>{for(int i=1;i<a.Length;i++)if(a[i-1]>0&a[i]>0)a[i]=a[i-1]+1;return a;};
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
a => {
    for( int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++ )
        if( a[ i - 1 ] > 0 & a[ i ] > 0 )
            a[ i ] = a[ i - 1 ] + 1;

    return a;
};
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;

namespace Namespace {
    class Program {
        static void Main( String[] args ) {
            Func<Int32[], Int32[]> f = a => {
                for( int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++ )
                    if( a[ i - 1 ] > 0 & a[ i ] > 0 )
                        a[ i ] = a[ i - 1 ] + 1;

                return a;
            };

            List<Int32[]>
                testCases = new List<Int32[]>() {
                    new Int32[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    new Int32[] { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    new Int32[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
                };

            foreach( Int32[] testCase in testCases ) {
                Console.WriteLine( $"{{ {String.Join(", ", testCase)} }}\n{f( testCase )}" );
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.0** - `75 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

- None

Comment: Since you are already modifying the input, you can change the `Func` into an `Action` and drop the `return a;`. Also, with Java/C# lambdas you don't have to include trailing semi-colon after the function. Your current code becomes: [`a=>{for(int i=1;i<a.Length;i++)if(a[i-1]>0&a[i]>0)a[i]=a[i-1]+1;}` (65 bytes)](https://tinyurl.com/y7qm32k3), but you could golf it further (by creating a port of [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167592/52210)) to: [`a=>{for(int p=0,i=0;i<a.Length;)a[i]=a[i++]<1?p=0:++p;}` (55 bytes)](https://tinyurl.com/ycrezebj).

Answer (score 1):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 152 bytes

```
	_ b _ F >
b
	dab
t
	dot
(
	t b
	t
X
	X dip
<
	b X (
/
	<
	< b
0
	t 0 b
>
	
	0
.
	dip <
	< b
	t b
x
	x .
H
	b b x >
	b
G
	t H /
	b b
F
	<
	F G
_
	_ b
	<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU4xDoQwDJvjV3hkgt6OGAtP6IaIujAV6Tr097m0QqdIiWPHSXLJ5WsmJ5UnIzcoJF@K6qVUTJBKpyoSJDHfD1aIMnHCAnG8uhz6VHCwQSABs5vvh686NjRI44yjm5XND4li79rBZZCIY1/kjhP9IW/NLNhnRHhz@DMjfg)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 217 Bytes

```
def f(d):
    c = 0
    r = []
    for e in d:
        if e == 1:
            r.append(1 + c)
            c += 1
        else:
            c = 0
            r.append(0)
    return r
```

I'm new so.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You can save bytes here by removing whitespace around operators, and using `;` instead of newlines for indentation. You can also save bytes by using `+=` instead of append.  Lastly instead of appending `1+c` and then incrementing `c` you can increment `c` first and then append it. [Here's a link with all those edits made](https://tio.run/##JcvBCoAgEATQs33FHpU6aEdjv0Q66S4JYbHZoa83KeYw8Jg5n7odZW4tEQPrZPygItpFMKyD4kOAIBdInVVmIETn44hukRFD7BNF@0X@u3SxXYTqLQWknZJL1ayDm/7Yv1dj2gs "Python 2 – Try It Online").  Anyway hope you have fun here!

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 73 bytes

```
var i=0
readLine()?.forEach{(it-48).toInt().let{c->i=i*c+c;print("$i ")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVD9vyyxSCHT1oCrKDUxxSczL1VD014vLb/INTE5o1ojs0TXxEJTryTfM69EQ1MvJ7WkOlnXLtM2UytZO9m6AGhIiYaSSqaCkmZt7f/a/waGhgZACAJgGsKEiwEBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <del>63</del> 54 bytes

```lua
function f(j)for i=2,#j do j[i]=j[i]*(j[i-1]+1)end end
```

Written by Jo King.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYZBCoMwEADvecViL7vtWkzveYl4SKOBBNmUJZ7Et6daKMMMs26@tbhJqKkIRMwUi0JyL75lmAvkMU3uyh3P9nZ6WFpkhtOm4GC3PLD9MfzvMCaikjEfTVKx@ve6PEOR4Csqd9wRtS8)

---

#### Explanation

```lua
function f(j) -- declares the function 'f' that will receive a variable 'j' (we know it's a table)
  for i=2,#j do -- from 2 to the number of elements in j
    j[i]=j[i]*(j[i-1]+1) -- change the current element of j to itself
              (j[i-1]+1) -- multiplied by the one before it plus one
  end
end
```

Original (invalid) in expanded form:

```lua
for i=2,#input do -- a loop that goes from 2 to the number of elements in the input table
  if input[i] == 0 then -- if the element at 'i' is 0
    input[i] = 0 -- then keep it as 0
  else
    input[i] = input[i-1]+1 -- change it to the element that comes before + 1
  end
end
```

Feel free to ask or suggest anything!

Comment: The input can't be a pre-declared variable, otherwise this is an incomplete snippet. Your submission can be either a full program taking input from STDIN or equivalent, or a function.

Comment: Here's a [54 byte function](https://tio.run/##NYZBCoMwEADvecViL7vtWkzveYl4SKOBBNmUJZ7Et6daKMMMs26@tbhJqKkIRMwUi0JyL75lmAvkMU3uyh3P9nZ6WFpkhtOm4GC3PLD9MfzvMCaikjEfTVKx@ve6PEOR4Csqd9wRtS8) that modifies its argument in-place. For more standards, you can check out the [Standard I/O methods for submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: @JoKing oh thank you for the correction, now I think I got how it works. But what do I do? Remove the post or edit it with your code?

Comment: You can use my code, sure

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

```cpp
[](auto&a){for(int&i:a)i*=*(&i-1)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVDBboMwDL3nK6xOqpJCV3IFirQ/2G2HtocopJ0lmqAQehhiv85SCkKl1XaaffGz33u2LMtyfZKye0EtizpXkKKpnFXinJGpd1HSGZsRstl8qKIIwX1iBaZ2Ze1AGk/xUBsHJ1McVQ7CgSgKQi4Gcyitkaqq3nT@blE7Wrk8jm@OqccZCAYNAR/9RHpbSFNY7DVAs7iWYhcdkp5xNJZ6DeCWJ5iK1wq/FGVJECCbqcNBiYPyftru9eLWF7UzcNx2uwO9lkvBmmHJEmPBcLVd0SWuOQt40nbDFVSwZ67f2f/e2xJyNTsL1HT82fy7DQ@jkPcZ9dUNRe1w8QN/Yo@asdPnH7ppA5/hO5cH3u/ePHye0aSxytVWQ@S/0v0A)

---

A lambda function which works with any int container supporting range-based for loops.

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 12 bytes

```
00000000: cd03 8030 0176 b928 0180 47d5            ...0.v.(..G.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSSUwyMFSwMjA0UDAzNzRSSLI0sgCwLAwUT8xRTBSSgp6dnoFemp6Gn5673/z8A) or [Run test cases.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BNy9VQT2mIjklpsLAOKbCwiCmwhiIDQxjKszNYiqSLGMqjCwgfJCciXlMRYqpuoKdQqJeUmYeF7IZQGlDGDJAYhigSkGRukKNgn5@QYl@lYVBen5Omn5xUTKMDTEcqKCiIuX/fwA)

I/O format is byte values.

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  call $8003    ; cd 03 80 ; a = getchar()
  jr nc, skip   ; 30 01    ; if not EOF, skip
  halt          ; 76       ; terminate program
skip:
  cp c          ; b9       ; compare a and 0
  jr z, skip2   ; 28 01    ; if a == 0, skip
  add b         ; 80       ; a += b
skip2:
  ld b, a       ; 47       ; b = a
  push de       ; d5       ; call putchar with return address 0
```

The final `push de` pushes the address 0 to the stack, so when `putchar` returns, PC goes back to the start of the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>74</strike> 70 bytes

```cs
a=>{int i=0;var s="";foreach(var c in a)s+=(i=c/49*-~i)+" ";return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU1BCsIwELz3FUtOibXagheJKYjgSS968BzSVBdqCtm0IKV@vaZIB4aZWZYZQ5lpvZ06QveE@4eCfUswjSaCIwwJBR3QwLlz5kDBx6f1X0qo1aRVOaALgCqXvfZAijFZxz5tXnw@GEAHWlCqOCqz3e1X2RdFyoBJb0PnHZAcJ7nM9C1WcNXouBgSADi1jtrGbh4eg@U1X/LN6uqCznIhhEzGccqLoojM89lE/AA)

*-4 bytes: changed format of* `foreach` *loop (thanks to [recursive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167573/consecutive-1-bits-are-incremented/175084?noredirect=1#comment421896_175084))*

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {
    int i = 0;              // initialize i to 0
    var s = "";             // initialize s
    foreach(var c in a)     // for each character in a
        s +=                    // append to s:
            ( i =                   // i, where i is:
                c / 49                  // ascii representation of c divided by 49 (identifies 0 or 1)
                    * -~i )             // multiplied by the negative bitwise complement of i (essentially, one more than current i)
            + " ";                      // a space
    return s;               // output s to console
}
```

Comment: Found 4 bytes to shave. https://tio.run/##NU1BCsIwELz3FUtOibXagheJKYjgSS968BzSVBdqCtm0IKV@vaZIB4aZWZYZQ5lpvZ06QveE@4eCfUswjSaCIwwJBR3QwLlz5kDBx6f1X0qo1aRVOaALgCqXvfZAijFZxz5tXnw@GEAHWlCqOCqz3e1X2RdFyoBJb0PnHZAcJ7nM9C1WcNXouBgSADi1jtrGbh4eg@U1X/LN6uqCznIhhEzGccqLoojM89lE/AA

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 62 bytes

```
#(map-indexed(fn[i n](*(+(.indexOf(reverse(take i %))0)1)n))%)
```

Use as follows:

```
(println #(...) [0 1 1 1 0 1])
```

where `#(...)` is the answer (anonymous function).

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 48 bytes

```forth
: f 0 tuck do 1+ over i + c@ '0 - * dup . loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCsIwEETvfsUjF8GSsuvRgvgvaaOikBBToV8fE63owDLLm531IeWLPftmpRzwCHl2N8aAdoTnlLjS4U5sBcuOcY703EOIDLUQ2TeSlzjRG7BHTP3iEsPmYRBVrSPSlipDXLHoB719Tb/sd6h/kgbLCw)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                \ start a new word definition
  0 tuck           \ set up a loop and also stick a 0 on the stack to use as a counter
  do               \ loop from 0 to string-length - 1
    1+             \ add 1 to counter
    over i +       \ get the address of the next character
    c@             \ get the ascii value for that character
    '0 -           \ subtract ascii 0 (48) from the value
    *              \ multiply counter by the result (change counter to 0 if char is '0')
    dup .          \ print the current sequence
  loop             \ end the loop
;                  \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 37 bytes

```
=SCAN(,array,LAMBDA(a,c,--IF(c,a+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
ĉᵐ∫j
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FiuPdD7cOuFRx-qsJcVJycVQ0QU3W6MNdAzB0ABKGujARMAwlivaAC6PLGOApMcQqziqKYboYgj1sRDXAAA)

A port of [@Dennis's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167594/9288).

```
ĉᵐ∫j
ĉ       Split into runs of equal elements
 ᵐ      Map over each run:
  ∫         Cumsum
   j    Join
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 41 bytes

```php
while(~$c=$argv[++$i])echo$k=++$k*$c," ";
```

takes input from command line arguments; prints string.

Run with `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

## Scheme, <s>91</s> 61 bytes

```scm
(lambda(l)(define x 0)(map(lambda(n)(set! x(* n(+ 1 x)))x)l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY1RCgIxDET/PcX4ZaII6ZGqTbXQloUq1tPXKlZwXZCBQGbyJuV41qT70zVEbeTUh6zwjaJNB2cp8vAqhCnZaSSZqehljUpbZNrBoDJz5cjceEUulCnaO8hjQ9LTp@Q9BcN5qXOgrLfY/yyj8oHNbP8q@rn7W2@wLJlh7QE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
\(×+1)
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAgXCjDlysxKQoKZiBbMCAxIDEgMSAwIDEgMSAwIDAgMCAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMV0KZiBbMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMCAxXQo=)

```
\(×+1)
\(   )  # scan by
   +1   # increment
  ×     # multiply
```