# Ragged index of

Tags: code-golf, ragged-list

Your input is a ragged list of positive integers and a positive integer. Your task is to find that positive integer and return it's index, or if the positive integer doesn't exist, indicate it's nonexistence.

How are indices in ragged lists defined? They are simply lists of indices that when used consecutively to index the ragged list, return the desired element. For example, if the ragged list is `[1,[2,3],[[4,5]],[]]` then the index of `2` is `[1,0]` and the index of `5` is `[2,0,1]`.

If there are multiple integers, return the index of the first one. That is, the one whose index is the smallest when compared lexicographically.

## Rules

You can choose between 0 and 1 based indexing and also the order of the returned index.

You must indicate the non-existance of a solution in some easily identified manner. Here are some examples:

### Ok

- Return a value that is not a list. For example, -1 or None
- Return an empty list
- Error in some way
- Exit the program

### Not ok

- Infinite loop/recursion (if you want to use a resource exhaustion error, be sure to read [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24411/using-resource-exhaustion-with-a-semi-deciding-algorithm?cb=1))
- Undefined behavior
- A list of integers, even if those integers are out of bounds or negative.

An exception to the last point. You may use a single consistent value that can never be the output to indicate nonexistence. For example, a program that returns `[-1]` whenever there is no solution is allowed, but a program that returns `[-1]` or `[-2]` when there isn't a solution is not allowed.

Finally, you can also return a list of all solutions in sorted order. If you use this IO format, you must return an empty list if there are no solutions.

## Test cases

```
[], 1 -> None
[[[40]]], 40 -> [0,0,0]
[[1,[]],[[3]],3,[3]], 3 -> [1,0,0]
[5], 5 -> [0]
[[],[[],[]]], 5 -> None
```

Comment: Does the consistency of the error value apply to all formats? For instance, can we return either `0` or `false` if there's no solution?

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241846/81203)

Comment: Can we return the list of *all* solutions?

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188162/matchmaker-matchmaker-make-me-a-match)

Comment: @WheatWizard Ok, I'll allow it as long as: 1. The list is sorted, 2. If there are no solutions, return the empty list.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 8 bytes

```
Position
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyC/OLMkMz/vf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXdbWhTrWRjnGtTnW1iY5pLZAGYqNaHRwypjhlzIAyQKlaHUOwEqCUQS1QGEiCuYZgRdXVxkDSWAdCgWVMYYZWg6TBZoFEuGr/AwA)

Built-in that returns all indices, 1-indexed. A very interesting answer, I'm sure.

---

To return the first such index:

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
FirstPosition
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYwxC4NADIV3/4bQKULP87q1OHUWOpYOhyhm8ATNFuJfv8aUjg55j7zv8eZI0zBHwj7m8Z6fuG7ULRsSLil3KyZ6l9VjbNvyc9lffUw7F8wOuAYvwNxAEHW9WuCEhFNyU6JIwFlF0VU0VrXXWYnZq3r4mZHwH@UD29aRFJK/)

Another built-in. Returns [`Missing["NotFound"]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) if `n` is not present. Almost as interesting as the above.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 14 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Returns an empty list if the value is not present. 1-based indexing.

```
∊(∊↑⍸⍤=)∘(↑⍣≡)
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TRpfGoo@tR28RHvTse9S6x1XzUMUMDzF38qHOhJgA&f=e9TVZKiQpvCob6pXsL@fgnp0rDrXo64mEwMUwehoE4PYWIiUMaqMoU50bKxOdLQxkDTWAVFgVaYoqkyxCUaDtMWCtMeqAwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

`↑⍣≡` Mix right argument until homogeneous (array). This converts the nested list to a rectangular array by inserting 0's.
`⍸⍤=` All indices where the left argument is equal to the resulting array.
`∊↑` Take 1 index if the left argument is present, 0 otherwise.
`∊` Flatten resulting list. This might not be necessary, but returning results with different levels of nesting seems wrong.

If returning an out-of-bounds index for the error case would be allowed, something like `⊃⍸⍤=∘(↑⍣≡)` could work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), <s>63</s> <s>62</s> 59 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)*

```python
f=lambda l,n,i=0:[i]+f(l[i],n)?[l[i]]*0+f(l,n,i+1)?l-n or[]
```

Returns the 0-based ragged index if found; raises an exception if not found. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728PKOyJCM_b8GCpaUlaboWN63TbHMSc5NSEhVydPJ0Mm0NrKIzY7XTNHKAlE6epn00iBGrZQASAinQNtS0z9HNU8gvio6FGqFYUJSZV6KRphFtqBNtpGMcqxMdbaJjGgukgVjBVFMTohBmJwA) Or, [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZBBTsMwFETFNqcYeRWTXylpGoSCoqzZcAHLi0BiNZJro8QRoKonYdMN4kxwGmzcwg42_49mnr7leX1_2r64rTXH49vi1Or640Y1utvd9x00GRqbvBajzFSq_SLDWxGEvMyDFYCs4K1eGdhJyHji8yJzw-weunmY0UAkSEVBEGtCKf0WG0IlgwpjzelvoPoPuIqAV0VUPs9lSDb5ySgokEKUfpb0vVDGrPp9QgREBvTkyUTZCXommGWH0eDnX3WCx2k0LlXs1vTDM6zC3kOHQO31fKgZPyMMjODbimc4WrA766DsYnrGY2fn-r8A).

#### Explanation

We define a recursive function `f` that takes three arguments:

- `l` is the object we're searching--usually a list, but could also be an integer at the bottom of the recursion
- `n` is the number we're searching for
- `i` is the current index in `l` that we're testing

We want to error if the number is not found; using Whython's `?` operator, we can catch any errors from deeper recursive calls and try the next case. As soon as we find the right number, we return a result instead of erroring. Or, once we run out of options, the error propagates back to the caller.

The function body has three cases, connected by `?`:

```python
[i]+f(l[i],n)
```

If `l` is a list and `i` is a valid index into that list, try recursing over `l[i]`. If that succeeds, it returns a list representing a ragged index, to which we prepend `i` and return. If the recursive call fails, or if `l` is not a list, or if `len(l) <= i` and therefore `i` is not a valid index into `l`, error and try the next branch:

```python
[l[i]]*0+f(l,n,i+1)
```

If `l` is a list and `i` is a valid index into that list, try recursing over the same `l` with `i+1`. If that succeeds, it returns a list representing a ragged index, to which we add an empty list and return. If the recursive call fails, or if `l` is not a list, or if `i` is not a valid index into `l`, error and try the next branch:

```python
l-n or[]
```

If `l` is an integer and is equal to `n`, we've found the number we're looking for; the difference is 0, so we return `[]`. If `l` is not an integer, `l-n` errors; if `l` is an integer not equal to `n`, returning some nonzero integer causes an error when we return from the recursive call and try to add the result to a list.

Comment: I don't think you need `[l[i]]*0+` (eventually breaks by recursion limit)

Comment: That is horrible and I love it. =P

Comment: I'm not sure whether relying on the recursion limit is allowed ([Relevant meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24412/64121))

Comment: @ovs Ah, that's a good point. We have to pretend there is no recursion limit in order to claim that the algorithm works with all possible inputs, so it's illogical to also base the algorithm on the existence of a recursion limit.

Comment: `l-n or[]` for -3: `l-n` errors when `l` is not a number, and `[i]+(l-n)` errors when it is.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
œi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Mz/h5frP2qYeXTSw50zNCP//4@OjtVRMFQAEtFAYGIQGwtkAikw31AnGsiNjjYGksY6YErBGCxlCiRNIYpACmJBCsFCAA)

Just the builtin. 1-indexed and outputs an empty list if not found.

Marginally less built in:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
=ŒṪṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/26KSHO1c93Nn0//By/UcNM0HcGZqR//9HR8fqKBgqAIloIDAxiI0FMoEUmG@oEw3kRkcbA0ljHTClYAyWMgWSphBFIAWxIIVgIQA)

1-indexed and outputs 0 if not found.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
dbĖ|ċʰiʰgᵗz↰ʰkᵗc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaaRx3LldISc4pT9ZRqH@7qrH24dcL/lKQj02qOdJ/akHlqQ/rDrdOrgGpPbcgGspL//4@Ojo7VUTBUABJAZrSJQWwskAmkwHxDnWggNzraGEga64ApBWOwlCmQNIUoAimIBSkEC8UCAA)

Input as a list `[list, item]`. Output 0-indexed, innermost index first, declarative failure if not found. There's definitely a byte or two left to shave off with all this list juggling, but it's already 5 down from how it started, so I'm giving it a rest for now.

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
h~t?bk|bB&hċi,B↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaaRx3LldISc4pT9ZRqH@7qrH24dcL/jLoS@6TsmiQntYwj3Zk6TkCl//9HR0fH6igYKgAJIDPaxCA2FsgEUmC@oU40kBsdbQwkjXXAlIIxWMoUSJpCFIEUxIIUgoViAQ)

This feels somehow worse.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 72 bytes

```
f(l,a)=if(l==a,[],#l'&&s=[concat(i,r)|i<-[1..#l],e!=r=f(l[i],a)],s[1],e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7RCsIwDPyVuMFsIR3OuTfrj4Q8hOGkUGbp9iL47zUrPiR3ucuRJMnBvVIpi4ko1gdF7wWJsY3nrts8ze91lt0EzPYb7o6Gvm8j4/Pks9dtCqxBxo0GFW2RlOLHCLgHpBzW3Yga0CA0IHRVdjgNLFXHqlmLQKQn4VCU0e3CrFShzoP@w0g0ah@xAozVmrRP/I/XqsGJ2ZYf)

1-indexed. Returns `e` if not found.

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 64 bytes

```
f(l,a)=if(l==a,,#l'&&s=[r*x+i|i<-[1..#l],e!=r=f(l[i],a)],s[1],e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUvNCsIwDH6VuMFcNRvO2Zv1RUIOOTgpFCmdBwXfvWbBQ77ffFlKHB651qVPKC5E5RAEsU37rlsDlcP7GL/xOtA0jm1ivO9CCfpFkXXAuNKkoauSc/r0AsMNconPVy9aQIPQgNBZ1dY0sFiOljmHQETqtkQVXU7MKpXMT0hqiWbFGY1gtsorev7P7WzomV39AQ)

Returns a polynomial whose coefficient list is the index, e.g., `[[1, []], [[3]], 3, [3]], 3 -> x^2 + x + 2`. I'm not sure if this is allowed.

1-indexed. Returns `e` if not found.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 54 bytes

```javascript
t=>g=a=>r=a.some?.((n,i)=>s=g(n)&&[i,...r])?s:a==t&&[]
```

Input the target and the array. Output an array or `false` if not found.

```js
f=

t=>g=a=>r=a.some?.((n,i)=>s=g(n)&&[i,...r])?s:a==t&&[]

console.log(f(1)([]))
console.log(f(40)([[[40]]]))
console.log(f(3)([[1,[]],[[3]],3,[3]]))
console.log(f(5)([5]))
console.log(f(5)([[],[[],[]]]))
```

## JavaScript 62 bytes

```javascript
a=>t=>JSON.parse(a,(x,y)=>y.some?.(x=>z=x)?x?x+[,z]:z:y==t&&x)
```

```js
f=

a=>t=>JSON.parse(a,(x,y)=>y.some?.(x=>z=x)?x?x+[,z]:z:y==t&&x)

console.log(f("[]")(1))
console.log(f("[[[40]]]")(40))
console.log(f("[[1,[]],[[3]],3,[3]]")(3))
console.log(f("[5]")(5))
console.log(f("[[],[[],[]]]")(5))
```

Input the array as JSON, and target value currying. Output a comma separated string or `false` if not found. It could be 58 bytes if a leading comma is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 75 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,l,h=[],t=0:f(n,l[0],h+[t])or f(n,l[1:],h,t+1)if[]<l else(l==n)*h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RasQgEEWfN18xb9HubNFm8xLqfkJ/YJBiqSGCayRru/Tr0zHbQBEUzz3XMf@UaU4v6zqa6K4fnw4SRpwMWSxGDaPgKymL05GKlfMCD6IHRliOWoaR7GsEH29eRGOSfJrW@xSiBz00h4AzGFjc/T2k/FWEfL7lGIpo4XSBVjaHiImFq8vCf7uIYc@RU47zElIBlrA9XVrchsuVPwe6vvA2J98Q0VlZy@ysKiSFvCxzjcSYqOO9w@2AblP0n9Iz6R@lWqiyraUdbwP63akF/F/5BQ)

Comment: Kinda funny that [several modifications](https://tio.run/##TY5BasMwEEXX8SlmZymZFCmONwb5CL3AIIpCHCxQZOGqDT29O3JiyGYE778/o/SXxymeluVmgrtfrg4iBsxG4X7sQk/Wxau4CYakLCrMzOU0wxPpzmI@6MIYimBMlPtxeYw@DKC7audxAgOze3z5mH6ykB/fKfgsajj2UMtqFzCycHdJDL8uoN9y5JTjNPuYgSWsj32N61W5kEXQZcPnFIeKiM7KWmZnVSAp/qeyzDUSY6KGZ4PrA82q6JfSMmmfpVIosi2lDa8H2s0pBXyv/AM) result in an exact tie.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 72 bytes (@att)

```
f=lambda L,n,*p:sum((f(l,n,*p,i:=i+1)for l in-1*L+L or[]),[p]*(i:=L==n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3PdJscxJzk1ISFXx08nS0CqyKS3M1NNI0csA8nUwr20xtQ820_CKFHIXMPF1DLR9tH4X8ouhYTZ3oglgtDaACH1vbPE1NqHlzCooy80qABkTH6igYamoqKCv45eelcsGFo6NNDGJjgZImBmDZaAMdIIxFUmCoEw2Uj442BpLGOmBKwRii1hBNrSlQyhRqDLIRIO2xIGPg8mBHQNwI8zsA)

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 75 bytes

```
f=lambda L,n,*p:[p]*(i:=L==n)+sum([f(l,n,*p,i:=i+1)for l in-1*L+L or[]],[])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XU9LCsIwEN17igE3SZtCQ1uQQk5g8AJDFhUNFmoSarvwLLroRu_kbUzTWooMzMD78ebxdvfuYs0wvPpOJ7vPXoumuh5PFUhmWORKdCoidSmkEIbGt_5KUJMmcMzDdcypti00UJuERzKWYFtUiqGic-TTtbXpiCaoGHBKYQsHa86bBUbMU-UtkKeBxZT5USsBZyESM78zFg5kk5b_aQtPFXPMOmK0j63UwocSU8ff-18)

1-based, outputs all matches.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3PdJscxJzk1ISFXx08nS0CqyKS3M1NNI0csA8nUwr20xtQ820_CKFHIXMPF1DLR9tH4X8ouhYTZ3oglgtDaACH1vbPE1NqHlzCooy80qABkTH6igYamoqKCv45eelcsGFo6NNDGJjgZImBmDZaAMdIIxFUmCoEw2Uj442BpLGOmBKwRii1hBNrSlQyhRqDLIRIO2xIGPg8mBHQNwI8zsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```ruby
f=->l,x{l*0==0?x==l:(x=l.index{|e|l=f[e,x]})&&[x,*l]-[1>0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCoNADEb3PUWgICpRRtRNIfYGvUDIoj8jFIIthcIU9ezTGbtoK4Fk8R5fvsfz9PK@p6JTdKPmhsjsHZHuUkdaXoeLdeNkJ6WeLTqZsyRhh7lKwVVnZPZ36MvzUTUFFoQKsm3RweE22M0PYW6MSOCNgQyiwQbDyJ9UIQeHuQ67xuVAvegBre02wPbzjVc5MUNi1leJhfwb)

f=->l,x{...}
Lambda taking *l* list, *x* element and return index or *nil*.

l*0==0?x==l:
if *l* is a value, return if it's the value, else:

(x=l.index{|e|l=f[e,x]})&&
*x* becomes index of{..} which may be nil, in that case return nil(falsely).
Block calls recursively *f* on each element returning *true* or an array of indexes( which are both truthy ), or false otherwise.

<s>[x,*l==1>0?[]:l]</s>  [x,*l]-[1>0]
else return that index and append *l*(next indexes) removing `true`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 99 bytes:

```
f=lambda l,t,c=[]:next((m for i,a in enumerate([l,[]][l*0==0])if(m:=f(a,t,c+[i]))),0)if l!=t else c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCgIhEIbvPcV00/Lg4i5E4JMMc7BNSVB3MYN6etOCaC8zzDf/x7@@ym1J6rTmWp0OJl6uBoIoYtZI52SfhbEIbsnghQGfwKZHtNkUyzAIJMJwkFpL4t6xeNaOmS4f0RPnXMiGIex1ARvuFua6Zp8KcwxJwMD57ncjjpKo0VFu8NBLBKJqU4nPAvWfmBqYNkqPU9e@n/oG)

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY3BCgIhEIbvPcV00/Lg4i5E4JMMc7BNSVB3MYN6etOCaC8zzDf/x7@@ym1J6rTmWp0OJl6uBoIoYtZI52SfhbEIbsnghQGfwKZHtNkUyzAIJMJwkFpL4t6xeNaOmS4f0RPnXMiGIex1ARvuFua6Zp8KcwxJwMD57ncjjpKo0VFu8NBLBKJqU4nPAvWfmBqYNkqPU9e@n/oG)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>62</s>  60 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

Expects `(value)(array)`. Returns *false* if not found.

```javascript
n=>g=(a,...o)=>a.map?a.some((v,i)=>g(v,...o,i))&&r:a-n?0:r=o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoMwDIbvewpPo4VaK@pFqL7BXiD0UFwVhzaiw9fv0rHD5mwgIcn/JenD7nbr1nF5ph7vLvQ6eN0MmlkhpUSuGytnu7RWbjg7xnYxUm2gGNuU8Ot1rW3qW1WvGkOHfsPJyQkH1rOcMzCcJ/8vy5Ibenf51ZeKAIBSGXPASA9KkJkDUkQiF2CMACjIFyIGoiOSnyEVIdXpWe8tZ3KI003c8s19PhFe)

Comment: `a.map` => `a[0]` given that only positive integer exist

Comment: [60](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoMwDIbvewpPo4VaK@pFqL7BXiD0UFwVhzaiw9fv0rHD5mwgIcn/JenD7nbr1nF5ph7vLvQ6eN0MmlkhpUSuGytnu7RWbjg7xnYxUm2gGNuU8Ot1rW3qW1WvGkOHfsPJyQkH1rOcMzCcJ/8vy5Ibenf51ZeKAIBSGXPASA9KkJkDUkQiF2CMACjIFyIGoiOSnyEVIdXpWe8tZ3KI003c8s19PhFe)

Comment: @l4m2 Ah, nice one. I never think of using that pattern.

Comment: [57](https://tio.run/##bc/BDsIgDAbgu0@xIySMQbZdSBhv4As0PZC5LRilxhlfH8F40Dma0Mv/UXr2T7@O93B71JFOU5ptinZYLPMicDt4UOi8XOk6sYU7sroJDoKQUhIaMsr4OjplyELANFJc6TLJCy1sZpozQM6r/9M01ZHidPjNdyoDgE4hbljOgxK5cEPaIrQARAHQ5rsVpWVdiN4jfSb97rfeU/biUF7HMuXbfZZILw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>95</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```julia
l::Int\n=l==n&&[]
l\n=for(i,v)=pairs(l);0∈(p=[i;v\n])||return p;end==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYo9CoMwFMd3T@EkCWRIiC7Kg649w8sbhFqaEqLEj3bwAJ6zF0kTaF3@n7/n6myv3jG6tr36xXhwAL6qkAqXyn0MzIqNw9TbMDPHO/k5DjYB2m4znvi@h2FZgy@nbvA3ABkv82N8lUhGFb@IWEsiMrU8FyWQSCDqpFpkM/p/NmSaE8wQZTiN8Qs)

Returns `false` for not found, 1-based indices for found.

`l::Int\n = l==n && []` - base case, when first argument is an Integer: if it's equal to the second argument, return empty Array `[]`; if it's not, return `false` (== 0).

`0 ∈ (p=[i;v\n]) || return p` - 1-based index `i` can never be 0, so if `[i; v\n]` contains a 0, that means the recursive call failed, move on. If `v\n` isn't 0, we found the number, so prepend the current index and return that back to the caller.

`==0` at the end - This check happens at the end of the loop and always returns `false` (thanks to @MarcMush for -1 byte by using this). If `for` loop completed without returning, we didn't find the number anywhere. So return `false` to indicate failure.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYo9CoMwFMd3T@EkCWRIUBfDg649w8sbhFqaEmKIH@3gATxnL5IaaF3@n7/n4myv3im5rrv62XhwAL6qkAp3lPsYmRUrh9DbODHHtfzsOwuAVq/GE9@2OMxL9GXQg78BqHSZHuOrRDKq@EXERhKRaeS5KIFEArE@tBbZTP0/WzLtCWaIMnyM6Qs "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: @MarcMush Thanks! Could you explain what a `for` loop's value as an expression actually is? It seems like it's always `nothing` (`for i=1:10; i; end == nothing` is `true`), but there must be more to it than that.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is always `nothing`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΔQƶʒZĀ}нZˆĀ*}¯¨
```

1-based. Results in `[[]]` if the ragged list doesn't contain the integer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3JTAY9tOTYo60lB7YW/U6bYjDVq1h9YfWvH/f7ShTrSRjnGsTnS0iY5pLJCOjeUyBQA) (Or [here a scuffed attempt to create a test suite..](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCqNL/c1NcIgKPbTs1KepIQ@2FvVGn2440RGjVHlp/aMV/Jb2wQ1tc0uMzgbwdtTr/o6OjDXWijXSMY3Wio010TGOBNBArmAJxdDSQMAQzgHIGsSBxIAXmG4KVRUcbA0ljHTClYAyWMoXrjgYpAJsHFooFAA))

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because there apparently is a bug with `Ā`  (Python-style truthify) incorrectly resulting in `1` for (some) empty strings..

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ           # Loop until the result no longer changes:
 Q          #  Check for each value in the ragged list if it's equal the to
            #  second (implicit) input-integer
            #  (will use the implicit first input-list in the first iteration)
  ƶ         #  Multiply each inner value by its 1-based index
   ʒ  }н    #  Find the first inner list which is truthy for:
    Z       #   Push the flattened maximum ("" if it lacks integers)
     Ā      #   Check if this is truthy (thus not 0 nor "")
        Z   #  Push the flattened maximum of the found list (without popping)
         ˆ  #  Pop and add it the global array
        Ā   #  Truthify the integers in the ragged list
         *  #  Multiply it by the second (implicit) input-integer
}¯          # After the loop: push the global array
  ¨         # Remove the last value, since the `Δ`-loop will have looped an
            # additional time before it stops; otherwise we could have printed
            # the flattened maximum directly instead of using the global array
            # (after which this list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 83 bytes

```perl
sub{($_,$n,@_)=@_;/\[/?push@_,0:/]/?pop:/,/?$_[-1]++:/^$n$/?return\@_:0for/\d+|./g}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFNT8JAEIbP9ldMyCKtLGwL1MM2tRy4mcjF23Zp0G4rEUrtR6JB/Os4W0CCErdJOzvzPvNOM7kqlu6OJP6urJ82Jokoyeg4svxx5LFQsCCvy5dxRG3OJF7WOWeUBSQSPUd2u5zNSEZYUKiqLrJwHHE7WRcsjLuffZZud55Rlwom82rO@aRe5arwAH0gXuUb7GHLYJ81sbHlf5UsLD89xtJCx7P@TYATCFbwOotVsjWwt2kIwCMkBQcuHP8OGvEpI@kBEWJkS4ngyP6NCJviI/8iDhVICDHE95A2HxjuEecy4qLCvTyYOMnPXbSD1E7n7H//8oNQ4fT77pHULgM6kmeItTF0tPowyVKvlyhcL4m8Q5ak/jVJTNwJ1i0UWPtKXiyyKmm1e7clwHJRVhzavYGLF8iaMNYq9Z6r50rFOuMMdDFda2UZZi1qXDVdlQXqDZowtSCAzvq1Axw6D9NHmN53jjI0BxwPDgw9EtTY7r4B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⟦⟧θ⟧ＦυＦＥ⁺⟦⟧§ι¹⟦⁺§ι⁰⟦λ⟧κ⟧⊞υκＩ⌊Φυ⁼⊟ιη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUzLCsIwELz7FTnuQgRLjz2JKHgo5L7sIdRKQ9NXHuLfx6QiOIcZmFc3aNct2qakoh8gSkHEUmyMzeG5OAERxa6tXkHZ6KHE53CfH/0bjBQVYt7syZ97KqblzCMjit/3mF@VM3OAi/YBWjObKU5wMzb0rhSuW9TWg1pWMHk8YEGTEhFVkpglUZ25ll/hdHzZDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `None` if the desired element is not present in the ragged array. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⟦⟧θ⟧Ｆυ
```

Start a breadth-first enumeration of all the elements and their ragged indices with the input list and an empty index.

```
ＦＥ⁺⟦⟧§ι¹⟦⁺§ι⁰⟦λ⟧κ⟧⊞υκ
```

If this element is a non-empty list then push all of its elements and their ragged indices to the search list.

```
Ｉ⌊Φυ⁼⊟ιη
```

Output the lexicographically earliest (if any) index of the desired element.