# Tips for golfing in Chef

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in Chef? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Chef (e.g. "remove unnecessary whitespace" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/tips-for-golfing-in-the-shakespeare-programming-language)