# Implement a Truth-Machine

Tags: code-golf

A **truth-machine** (credits goes to [this guy](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Keymaker) for coming up with it) is a very simple program designed to demonstrate the I/O and control flow of a language. Here's what a truth-machine does:

- Gets a number (either 0 or 1) from STDIN.
- If that number is 0, print out 0 and terminate.
- If that number is 1, print out 1 forever.

## Challenge

Write a truth-machine as described above in your language of choice. The truth-machine must be a full program that follows these rules:

- take input from STDIN or an acceptable alternative

  - If your language cannot take input from STDIN, it may take input from a hardcoded variable or suitable equivalent in the program
- must output to STDOUT or an acceptable alternative

  - If your language is incapable of outputting the characters `0` or `1`, byte or unary I/O is acceptable.
- when the input is `1`, it must continually print `1`s and only stop if the program is killed or runs out of memory
- the output must only be either a `0` followed by either one or no newline or space, or infinite `1`s with each `1` followed by either one or no newline or space. No other output can be generated, except constant output of your language's interpreter that cannot be suppressed (such as a greeting, ANSI color codes or indentation). Your usage of newlines or spaces must be consistent: for example, if you choose to output `1` with a newline after it all `1`s must have a newline after them.
- if and only if your language cannot possibly terminate on an input of `0` it is acceptable for the code to enter an infinite loop in which nothing is outputted.

Since this is a catalog, languages created after this challenge are allowed to compete. Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed (and even encouraged) to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language. Other than that, all the standard rules of [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) must be obeyed. Submissions in most languages will be scored in bytes in an appropriate preexisting encoding (usually UTF-8).

## Catalog

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 320px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 62732; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 12012; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: Can we assume that the program halts when the processor finishes executing the written code, for a machine code entry?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes.

Comment: Assuming any behaviour is fine for all invalid inputs?

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, the only inputs you should expect to get are 0 and 1.

Comment: Is it alright if I just have single spaces between the `1`s?

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Sure. I'll add that to the rules.

Comment: Catalog is borked.

Comment: Catalog appears to consider `Bf` and `bf` to be different languages.

Comment: Without having looked at all of them, I suspect a significant number of entries here to be expecting inputs of "0\n" or "1\n". I expect this was expected by @quartata but it's not necessarily explicit in the challenge. Is there a standard definition of "input a number" somewhere on meta?

Comment: Are non-zero exit codes ok? Also, can I forgo a space that would normally separate the `1`s? (i.e. `11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`) I assume not for the second question.

Comment: is exiting with an error allowed?

Comment: @12Me21 This is allowed by default on all challenges.

Comment: Is taking input as \x00 and \x01 over STDIN allowed?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline "If your language is incapable of outputting the characters 0 or 1, byte or unary I/O is acceptable."

Comment: Well, my language does allow that, so :( RIP Newbiefuck, 4 bytes: `,[.]` I/O as \x00 and \x01

Comment: While attempting this, I made [a program](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1XBxFI3XqGaizO8KLMEzNMAiWhy1f7/bwAA) that does just the opposite, when given zero it prints out infinite zeroes, and when given 1, does nothing

Comment: Can the form of `1` change—is `1 1/1 1/1 1/1...` allowed?

Comment: Is one allowed to print an infinite number of `1`s? That is, not print out `1`s forever, but print out an infinite list of `1`s all at once? This would be theoretically demonstrated, but the language has no notion of printing more than once. It just generates an output. So is it okay if it runs indefinitely, but would print infinite `1`s given infinite time (to finish executing)?

Answer (score 202):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 6 bytes

This was surprisingly tricky, <s>and I'm not convinced it's optimal...</s>

```
<.@!$?
```

After padding and unfolding the code, this represents the following hex grid:

[image]

This uses a similar control flow [like my recent error-free cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62306/8478), moving along anti-diagonals. To achieve that we start by deflecting the instruction pointer (IP) to the left, where the purple path wraps around to the lower left corner.

`?` reads the input as an integer. `!` prints it back. `.` is just a no-op. Now the corner of the grid acts as a branch:

If the input was `0`, the IP will continue along the red path, which simply terminates the program with `@`.

If the input was `1`, the IP will continue on the green path. Again, `.` is just a no-op, but `$` is the equivalent of Befunge's trampoline: it skips the next instruction. After wrapping, the next instruction would be the `?`, but due to `$` execution actually continues on the blue path, starting with `!` to print another copy of the `1`. This loop which only contains `!..$` is now repeated indefinitely.

#### A study of control flow in Hexagony...

I believe the above solution is optimal. I've written a brute forcer, which checks all 6-byte Hexagony programs, which contain at least one each of `?!@` (which are necessary; I've also checked `:` and `%` in place of `@` to terminate with a division-by-zero error, but that didn't help either). The check prints all the programs which a) produce a `0` on input `0` and terminate and b) produce at least two `1`s (and nothing else) and *don't* terminate within the first 60 ticks of the program (200 ticks for 5-byte solutions). I doubt that any valid solution would take more than 200 ticks to correctly print the first `0` or the second `1` on such a small grid, so I don't think I've missed out on any potential solutions.

The search didn't yield any results for 5 bytes, but 57 results for 6 bytes (using `@`; there's no need to terminate with an error if we can solve this cleanly in the same amount of bytes). Of those 57 only 6 were false positives which actually printed only two `1`s and then entered an infinite loop without printing any more. One solution was listed twice because it contained two `!` commands. That leaves exactly 50 valid solutions.

There is a certain amount of degeneracy between the solutions where one or two characters are not substantial, e.g. because they're effectively no-ops anyway. The solutions can be grouped into 23 sets of genuinely distinct programs (in some cases, there is only a single character difference between two sets, but it changes the control flow substantially, so I've counted them separately). Two of the groups even make use of multiple instruction pointers in a very unexpected way. As I would never have come up with most of these ways to use the branches and mirrors, they make a very interesting study of what sorts of control flow are possible in Hexagony, and I have definitely learned some new tricks for future golfs.

The *overall* control flow is almost always the same: read a number, print it. If it's `0` find a way to the `@`, if not keep looping through the `!` while mainting an edge value of `1`. There are four notable exceptions:

- One solution (the one with two `!`) prints two `1`s per iteration through the grid, therefore printing about twice as fast as the majority of programs. I've marked this one with `x2` below.
- A few solutions (those which contain an `o`) replace the `1` with a `111` (the character code of `o`), so they print *three* `1`s per iteration, making them print about three times as fast as the majority of programs. I've marked these with `x3` below.
- Two solutions *append* a `1` to the edge value in each iteration (so `1` --> `11` --> `111` --> ...). Those print *very* fast, but they'll run out of memory eventually. I've marked these with `OoM` below.
- Two solutions enter a very tight loop which merely bounces back and forth over the `!`, printing on every other tick (instead of of every 5th or so), which makes them slightly faster (and neater). I've marked these with `><` below.

So here is the entire zoo:

```
#1                #5                #12                #19
?!/$.@            ?$!>$@            .?!/$@             |!|?$@  # ><
?!/$1@  # OoM     ?$!|$@            =?!/$@
?!/$=@                                                 #20
?!/$\@            #6                #13                $@.?<!
?!/$o@  # x3      ?/!<|@            .?/!$@             $@1?<!  # OoM
?!/$!@  # x2                        =?/!$@             $@=?<!
                  #7                                   $@o?<!  # x3
#2                ?\!<|@            #14
?!>$)@                              \!?__@             #21
?!>$1@            #8                                   _>_!?@
?!>$o@  # x3      ?<!>$@  # ><      #15
?!|$)@                              \_?!$@             #22
?!|$1@            #9                                   <!@.$?
?!|$o@  # x3      ?\$!@$            #16                <!@/$?
                                    \_?!_@             <!@=$?
#3                #10                                  <$@!$?
?!|)$@            ?~#!@)            #17                <.@!$?
?!|1$@            ?~#!@1            $$?\@!             </@!$?
?!|o$@  # x3                                           <=@!$?
                  #11               #18
#4                ?$)\@!            \$?\@!             #23
?_!<@>            ?$1\@!                               <<@]!?
                  ?$o\@!  # x3
```

The following is a short walkthrough for a handful of the more representative groups. Especially groups 10 and 23 are worth checking out. There are many other interesting and sometimes convoluted paths in the other groups, but I think I've bored you enough at the end of this. For anyone who really wants to learn Hexagony, these are definitely worth investigating though, as they exhibit even more possible uses of the mirrors and `$`.

**Group 1**

This one isn't much more elaborate than my original solution, but the paths go in different directions. It also allows for the largest number of variations in a single cell, as the right-most no-op can be replaced with 5 different commands which still make this valid without changing the structure:

[image]

**Group 2**

This one is quite interesting, because it only moves horizontally. After wrapping to the `>`, the IP reverses immediately, taking the branch in the corner. It's not entirely well visibly no the diagram, but in the case of the `1` we traverse the first row again, but backwards this time. This also means we run into `?` again, which now returns `0` (EOF). This is fixed with `)` (increment) to keep printing `1`s. This also has 5 variations, as `)` could also be `1` or `o`, and `>` could also be `|`:

[image]

**Group 3**

This one looks almost identical to the previous one but it's messy as hell. Up to hitting `|` and then traversing the bottom or top row it's the same. But in the case of a loop, the `$` now skips over the `)` *onto* the mirror. So we follow the turquoise path to the right, now hit the increment, skip over the `@` before we wrap around to the `|` *again* and *then* go back to the green path at the top.

[image]

**Group 4**

I thought this one was particularly nifty:

[image]

The `_` mirror in the top right corner is initially a no-op, so we print with `!` and hit the `<`. The `0` path now hits the horizontal mirror and terminates. The `1` path takes a really interesting trajectory though: it deflects down, wraps to the `!`, gets redirected towards the horizontal and then wraps back to the `!` *again*. It then keeps moving in this rhombus shape, printing twice per iteration (every third tick).

**Group 8**

This is one of the two solutions with a really tight printing loop:

[image]

The `<` acts as the branch. After wrapping twice, `0` hits `@`. `1` on the other hand, first skips the `?`, then `>` sends it onto the the `$` again, so that is skips the `@`. Then the IP wraps into the turquoise path, where it bounces back and forth between the `>` and `<` (wrapping around the edge in between).

**Group 10**

One of two groups which use other instruction pointers, and it's absolutely beautiful. Hexagony has 6 - each one starts from a different corner along the clockwise edge, but only one of them is active at a time.

[image]

As usual, we read with `?`. Now `~` is unary negation: it turns the `1` into a `-1`. Next, we hit the `#`. This is one way to switch between IPs: it takes the current edge value modulo 6 and switches to the corresponding IP (IPs are numbered from `0` in the clockwise direction). So if the input was `0`, then the IP simply remains the same, and travels boringly straight ahead into `!@`. But if the input was `1`, then the current value is `-1` which is `5 (mod 6)`. So we switch to the IP which starts on the very same cell (the green path). Now `#` is a no-op and `?` sets the memory edge to `0`. `)` increments so `!` prints a `1`. Now we hit `~` again to ensure that `#` is still a no-op (as opposed to switching us to IP 1 which would terminate the program). It's mindblowing how well everything fits together in this little program.

**Group 22**

Just to note, this is the group my original solution is in. It also happens to be largest group, because the no-op can be in two different places, and there are several choices for the actual (effective no-op) command.

**Group 23**

This is the other group using multiple IPs. In fact this one uses *3* different IPs. The top right corner is a bit of a mess, but I'll try to walk you through this:

[image]

So, the beginning you've seen before: `<` deflects North-East, `?` reads input. Now `]` is another way to change between IPs: it hands control to the next IP in clockwise order. So we switch control to the turquoise path which (I know it's hard to see) starts in the North-East corner going South-East. It is immediately reflected by the `<` so that it wraps to the South-East corner, going North-West. It *also* hits the `]` so we switch to the *next* IP. This is the grey path starting in the East corner, going South-West. It prints the input, then wraps to the North-East corner. `<` deflects the path into the horizontal, where it is reflected by the *other* `<`. Now the right-hand `<` acts as a branch: if the input was `0`, the IP moves North-East, and wraps to the `@`. If the input was `1`, the IP moves to the `!`, wraps to the lef-thand `<` where it is reflected... now in the corner, it wraps back to the `!`, gets deflected by the the right `<`, reflected by the left `<` and the paths starts over...

Quite a mess, but a beautiful mess. :)

---

Diagrams generated with [Timwi's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi) amazing [HexagonyColorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer).

Comment: whoa. just whoa.

Comment: @ThomasOltmann I admit this answer assumes some basic knowledge of the language. If you're actually interested in learning more about it, I've gone through the basics [in this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57600/8478) and [in this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57706/8478), but I won't blame you if you're not. ;)

Answer (score 157):

## [Motorola MC14500B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_MC14500B) Machine Code, 2 bytes

In hex:

```
58EC
```

Explanation:

```
5  OR the register with input from the data bus
8  Write the register to the data bus
E  Skip next instruction if register is zero
C  Jump
```

The Motorola MC14500B is a 1-bit microcontroller; it has one 1-bit register and a 1-bit data bus. Since the opcodes are 4 bits each, there are only sixteen; half of them carry out a logical operation between the register and the bit on the data bus.

The jump instruction sets a jump flag; when no address is provided, it is common to set the program counter to 0. If the input bit was zero, the processor will not jump. If the input bit was 1, the processor jumps back to the start; since we're `OR`ing with input, it doesn't matter what the input signal is afterwards—the register will then be 1 forever.

As is conventional, the register is initialized to 0.

A list of the opcodes can be found on the data sheet, or [here](https://www.brouhaha.com/%7Eeric/retrocomputing/motorola/mc14500b/).

Comment: 2 bytes is definitely the minimum for this challenge.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I've been looking for several hours through esolangs and lists of 4-bit processors to see if there's a 1 or 1.5, and haven't found one.

Comment: Definitely the right tool for the job.

Comment: Link is borked atm...

Comment: @TheDoctor Both links work fine for me

Comment: @Mego he must have changed it... It was another site yesterday

Comment: Is there a simulator for MC14500B that I can try?

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I think this wouldn't halt even if the input is 0, according to the handbook. Refer to page 11 of the handbook: [`The PC counts up sequentially in binary to its highest value and "wraps around" to zero and counts up again.`](http://www.brouhaha.com/~eric/retrocomputing/motorola/mc14500b/mc14500b_icu_handbook.pdf)

Comment: @petStorm That quote is an example of one possible configuration for the microcontroller. Another possible configuration could have it execute a finite program, which is what I was implicitly assuming. If it does wrap around, `58AB` would still work for 2 bytes by disabling the input and output pins after one output on input 0.

Answer (score 92):

### Arnold C, 296 Bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i    
    YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
    BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE i
        STICK AROUND i
            TALK TO THE HAND i
        CHILL
    BULLSHIT
        TALK TO THE HAND i
    YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Not really competitive, but for the fun of it.
Does not support stdin, replace `@NO PROBLEMO` with `@I LIED` for a zero value. `@No Problemo` is 1.

Run with (assuming file is truthmachine.arnoldc):

```
wget http://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC.jar
java -jar ArnoldC.jar truthmachine.arnoldc
java truthmachine
```

Comment: Beautiful. I cried 10/10

Comment: @ThomasKwa I think you have to use tabs for it to parse correctly. I haven't used this language in a while though, could be wrong.

Comment: `BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE` LOL

Comment: It looks like this does `if(i){while(i) print(i);} else {print(i);}` Surely it would be shorter to do `print(i);while(i) print(i);`?

Comment: Although `BULLSHIT` has a great contribution to the entertainment value of the program, technically it is unnecessary. You can factor the whole `BULLSHIT` branch out by moving `TALK TO THE HAND i` after `YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC`.

Comment: @GaborSch There is only one proper response to that: `BULLSHIT` ;)

Comment: @user00001 `YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC` :D

Answer (score 74):

## Minecraft, 18 Bytes (MC Version 15w45a)

[image: minecraft sketch]

As you can see, there is a lever directed into the repeating command block, which has the command `say 1` in it. There is an signal inverting torch on top of that, which directs power into the single-run command block with the command `say 0` in it.

Whenever the switch is directed towards truthy, the repeater block uses the code `say 1` to output infinite `1`s. When the lever is redirected to false, it outputs a single `0`.

Note that this outputs a `[@]` by default. If you *really* want just straight up 1s and zeros, this becomes 34 bytes, where the code in the command blocks are `tellraw @a [1]` and `tellraw @a [0]`. This is using @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ's suggested byte count for MC [as can be found in Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7397/44713).

Comment: You used a video game for code golf. +1

Comment: @RK. This is actually fairly standard practice for simple challenges. There are at least two other users who use MC as a code golfing language - try the search bar with `is:answer Minecraft`. c:

Comment: @FlagAsSpam lol nicely done. Also, thanks for that tip to search MC answers.

Answer (score 66):

## Bash + GNU utils, 13

```
grep 0||yes 1
```

---

## Bash, 35

```
read n;for((;n;));{ echo 1;};echo 0
```

Comment: You know, I was wondering if a bash solution with yes would be possible...

Comment: Nice! That's pretty clever

Answer (score 43):

## Microscript, 3 bytes

```
i{p
```

The shortest one I know.

Explanation:

```
i  Takes numeric input and puts it in register 1
{  while register 1 is truthy
  p  Print the contents of register 1
```

Microscript has implicit printing of register 1 upon termination, which is the reason why an input of `0` gets printed once.

Comment: @quartata I matched you :D

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ :O

Comment: I'm seriously wondering if you wrote the question first, or the answer...

Comment: The question. I just wanted to post this since it was the shortest one I came up with while writing the question. It is a catalog so there aren't any real winners.

Answer (score 41):

## Ruby, 20

```
print while/1/||gets
```

Run from the command line to avoid warnings, as

```
ruby -e "print while/1/||gets" <<< 0
ruby -e "print while/1/||gets" <<< 1
```

Explanation:

Less golfed, this is

```
while /1/ || gets
  print
end
```

When a Regexp is used in a conditional, it evaluates as falsey unless the variable `$_` is populated and matches the pattern. On the first time through the loop, `$_` is empty so we fall through to `gets`, which sets the value of `$_` to a line read from STDIN. `print` with no arguments prints `$_`. Now we evaluate the conditional again. If we read in 1, we short-circuit and just print 1 again, and so on forever. Otherwise, we fall through to `gets`, but since there's no second line of input, `gets` returns nil, so the loop ends.

Comment: It's nice when trivial tasks still allow mindblowing solutions even in "normal" languages. :)

Comment: The `||gets` part is cool and all, but can't you just do `gets;print while/1/` and save a byte?

Comment: No, then it doesn't print the 0 at all.

Answer (score 38):

## Turing Machine Code, <s>32</s> 22 bytes

Using the rule table syntax found [here.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html)

```
0 0 0 * halt
0 * 1 r 0
```

Comment: I really like this. +1

Comment: I knew someone would've already posted this!

Answer (score 31):

### Python 2, 29 bytes

```python
a=input()
while 1:print a;1/a
```

This terminates with a division error on `0`, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/20260).

Comment: STDERR output is fine. The ><> answer uses it as well.

Comment: This is brilliant ^_^

Comment: Would while a print a work? Sorry, I dont know python.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala For 0, it wouldn't print anything, but it should print it once.

Comment: @xnor oh, my bad.

Comment: A new user (@SeoFernando) suggested a golf, replacing `a;a/1` with `a/a`.

Answer (score 30):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

[For loops are often shorter than while loops.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2695/45393)

`alert(x)` returns `undefined`, which is falsy, so the bitwise or operator, `|`, casts it to `0`. Thus, if `x` is `"0"`, alert once, otherwise keep looping. Uses `alert` for STDOUT like [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62742/45393).

```
for(x=prompt();alert(x)|x;);
```

Comment: Shoot, you beat me to it. I was about to post exactly this! :) GG

Comment: Wow, that's a good bit more clever than mine :) Have a +1!

Comment: You don't need the trailing semicolon.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ What browser did you use? I tested it on Firefox and Chrome and I get a `SyntaxError` without it.

Comment: @intrepidcoder Oh, sorry, my bad. My mind was in "trailing semicolons are useless" mode. ^^"

Comment: Yeah, you need one because it's a for loop. :)

Comment: Nice job, placing the alert in the condition was clever

Comment: `e=>{do{alert(e)}while(e)}` 25 bytes

Answer (score 22):

## Pyth, <del>4</del> <del>3</del> 2

```
Wp
```

There is <s>a</s> no! trailing space (thanks isaac :) ). The space used to be required to make the while loop compile, but Pyth has since been updated. Normally that would disqualify using it, but since this is a catalog it should be valid.

#### Explanation:

```
Wp        : implicit Q = eval(input)
W         : while
 p        : print and return the value of Q, to be evaluated as the while condition
          : Functions without enough arguments automatically use Q now
          : do nothing in the body of the while loop
```

Comment: I was inspied by this answer to add implicit `pass` to Pyth. The space is now unnecessary. https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=WpQ&input=0&debug=0

Comment: Crossed four still looks like a four.

Comment: Eh, I'm just getting so bored of seing pyth dominate everything all the time :(. LOL.

Comment: @AshwinGupta [my language](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66601/41042) technically beat it, so it's not completely dominating :)

Comment: @Cyoce yeah! Good job! I rest assured that something can beat pyth lol.

Comment: @AshwinGupta [my other language](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/69837#69837) did too :D

Comment: `Wp` now works.

Comment: @muddyfish Thanks for the reminder, edited! :)

Comment: @AshwinGupta [My language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/197035#197035) beats both of Cyoce's languages.

Answer (score 22):

## Brainfuck, <s>41</s> <s>36</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

Shortened by printing once right after input and with help from Ethan and user46915.

```
,.+++[->>+<-----<]>>---<-[>.<]
```

Previous version: Subtract 48 from the input, and if it's not zero, add 1 to the 48 to print ASCII `1` forever, otherwise print `0`.

```
-[>+<-----]>--->,<[->->+<<]>[>+<]>.<[>.<]
```

I ran it [**here**](http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html), but due to buffered output, you cannot see any output since the program never terminates on `1`.

Edit: I had forgotten to print `0` on input `0`. Fixed now. I like the `>.<` faces at the end.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I'm guessing not, but I'm not sure since I don't see an algorithm specifically for modulo 2. The [divmod algorithm](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Divmod_algorithm) is a little long.

Comment: You can shorten it a bit more by merging the pieces of code together a bit better and directly using your input register instead of having a separate "48" register:
`,.[>+>+<<-]-[>-<-----]>+++[>.<]`

Comment: Attempted a solution with mod 2.  Definitely looks like subtracting 48 is the right way to go.  `,.[->+>+<<]>>[->[>-<[-]]>+[<+>-]<<]>[<<.>>]`

Comment: You might want to mention that this assumes 8 bit cells with wraparound on underflow, in case anyone is trying to run it on an interpreter that works differently.

Comment: @Ray That's the default and is generally assumed. Had I used another implementation, I would've said so.

Comment: I like it when emoji appear in my code, too.

Comment: You can get one more byte off by combining subtraction and copying together: `,.+++[->>+<-----<]>>---<-[>.<]`

Answer (score 20):

## Piet, <strike>27</strike> <strike>18</strike> 16 codels

(Codel is a fancy name for pixel used to avoid confusion when an image is stretched for viewing. I counted codels instead of bytes because piet scripts are saved as images, so the physical size may vary. I think an ideal file format that would save this piet as efficiently as possible would take 11 bytes. In practice, my tiny gif file is 62 bytes, with optimal palette data. Tell me if I should use this as the size of my entry instead of the codel amount.)

Original image: [image: tiny version]

Enlarged: [image: enlarged version]

In piet, the difference between two colors is what determines which command runs, so seeing the same color twice doesn't mean it does the same action. The execution begins in the top-left codel. Then it moves horizontally, performing the following:

1. Read a number and put it on the stack
2. Duplicate the top of the stack
3. Pop and output the top of the stack
4. Pop the top of the stack and rotate clockwise that number of times.

If the input was 1, the cursor then moves down into the lime codel, which pushes 1 on the stack. Then the execution continues going left. When the cursor passes from a color to white and from white to a color, nothing happens. Since black is considered as walls too, the cursor ends up going back to the lime codel on the top line, and repeats the whole thing from step 2.

If, however, the input was 0, the cursor will never go down and will end up in the blue J on the right (pun intended, it was worth it), were it will stay trapped (because the top, right, left and bottom sides of this J-shaped block are next to black codels or the edge of the image). Since the cursor is trapped, execution ends.

**Unexpected values:**
If the user writes another number, it will still be printed, then the cursor will rotate more or less times based on the value.

- Multiple of 4 or 0: execution continues horizontally and ends.
- Multiple of 3: Since going up is impossible, the cursor immediately rotates clockwise and continues horizontally, then ends.
- Multiple of 2 and not a multiple of 4: the cursor rotates and starts moving to the left. Luckily, all this does is perform a bunch of operations that don't affect the program flow and end up emptying the stack. When an operation can't be done because the stack is empty, it is simply ignored. When it hits the top left corner, the cursor has nowhere else to go but to the right again, effectively restarting the program.
- Other values: The cursor goes down as if it would with 1, which makes it print 1 forever. If the input is 5, the output will be `5111111111111...`

Any non-integer value will terminate the program. Execution will continue normally, but all operations will be ignored since there is nothing in the stack. So in a way, the program never crashes - it either stops normally or loops forever.

---

**PietDev friendly version**

PietDev (a very basic online Piet IDE) seems to have trouble with white codels so I made a new version which manually rotates back up instead of relying on proper white codel automatic rotation. And I didn't even need to use a new color! If you want to test with it, make sure you draw a black border around the code because PietDev doesn't support custom program sizes.

[image: tiny version]

[image: enlarged version]

---

**Older versions**

The first version didn't push 1 back on the stack and instead looped back to an earlier duplication instruction. It also had decorative useless codels.

[image: Tiny pattern which is actually a piet code]

[image: Enlarged version]

Then I had the idea to push 1 on the stack to remove the blank line. It's funny how I thought of it thanks to my decorative codels.

[image: tiny version]

[image: large version]

Then I realized I had an extraneous dup that wasn't needed anymore, and I reduced the number of colors to save up on palette data in the image. I also got rid of the single decorative codel because I don't know.

Comment: I've never seen a Piet answer scored in anything other than codels, but I think the optimal byte count is also interesting to include :)

Comment: There are 20 different codel values, which means you should be able to pack three codels into 13 bits, then eight triplets into 13 bytes for a storage density of 2.6 codels per byte. But someone has to define that language first. I suggest the name DPPi = densely packed piet.

Comment: @JanDvorak I counted 21 values to add a special one for line break, and once you're got the first line break the parser can guess where the other ones should be. But I didn't go as far as combining codels into triplets, which makes much more sense than wasting 5 bits per codel. Clever.

Comment: Just add the dimensions as the first couple of bytes. You don't need an extra symbol.

Comment: @everyone who wants to try it out: Don’t try this solution with PietDev because PietDev only prints a single 1 and terminates. But the solution works properly with npiet.

Comment: @ML Indeed, PietDev doesn't implement white codels correctly it seems.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, I think it might be the cc that’s not implemented properly? And another problem is that PietDev uses float division instead of integer division.

Comment: @ML Good to know. Here, I edited the post and added a PietDev friendly version.

Comment: If you count each [codel reasonably](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%2820%29), a "comparable score" for this answer would be **~69.15 bits** (or ~8.64 bytes, less humorously)

Answer (score 19):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 6 bytes

```
e*faAs
```

Chip is a 2D language that behaves a bit like an integrated circuit. It takes input, one byte at a time, and breaks out the bits to individual input elements. Output stitches the values of output elements back together into bytes.

Let's break this down:

`*` is a source signal, it will send a true value to all adjacent elements.
`e` and `f` correspond to the fifth and sixth bit of the output.
So, `e*f` produces binary `00110000`, which is ASCII char "0".

Now, `A` is the first bit of input and `a` is the first bit of output, so `aA` copies that bit from input to output. So, when combined with `e*f`, an input of ASCII "0" produces "0", and "1" produces "1". (There is no interaction between `f` and `a`, since neither produce any signal.)

The `s` on the end, when activated by a true signal, will prevent input from advancing to the next byte, meaning that the whole thing will run again with the same input.

Since the first byte of "0" is zero, it won't activate this element and the program will print "0", and thereby exhaust its input, which allows it to terminate. "1", however, activates this element, which means that "1" is output, but not consumed on the input, allowing the cycle to repeat indefinitely.

If values 0x0 and 0x1 are used for output, rather than ASCII, we can eliminate the `e*f` part, resulting in only **3 bytes**:

```
aAs
```

If the zero must terminate itself, rather than expecting stdin to close, we get the following, which inverts the first byte with `~`, and passes the result to `t`, which terminates the program (**10 bytes**):

```
aA~te*f
 s
```

(`t` also produces no signal, so there is no interaction between `t` and `e`.)

Comment: Nice answer! Since this is a catalog challenge, there's no need to mark this as non-competing, so I've removed that bit for you. Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding Chip to TIO. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@5@qlZboWPz/vyEA "Chip – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Dennis, question for you: how would I get TIO to update its source? Last week I fixed a bug in the Chip interpreter, but it hasn't propagated the change into TIO. Is this something I need to ask someone to do for me?

Comment: I've pulled Chip. If you need something updated, just leave a message in http://talk.tryitonline.net.

Answer (score 16):

## [Brainbool](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainbool), 5 bytes

```
,.[.]
```

Brainbool is Brainfuck, but it only operates on bits, and does I/O through `0` and `1` characters.

Comment: I knew there had to be a BF derivative where this could be feasibly done.

Comment: I feel like "Boolfuck" might be a better name for it, but well done regardless.

Comment: @JamesMurphy it seems that exists already: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck

Answer (score 15):

## LOLCODE, 119 bytes

```
GIMMEH n
n R SUM OF n AN 0
BOTH SAEM n AN 0, O RLY?
YA RLY
 VISIBLE 0
NO WAI
 IM IN UR l
  VISIBLE 1
 IM OUTTA UR l
OIC
```

Ungolfed:

```
HAI

BTW, Read n as a string from STDIN and convert to an integer
GIMMEH n
n R SUM OF n AN 0

BTW, Test n for equality with 0
BOTH SAEM n AN 0, O RLY?
YA RLY
    BTW, Write 0 to STDOUT and exit
    VISIBLE 0
NO WAI
    BTW, Loop forever, printing 1
    IM IN YR l
        VISIBLE 1
    IM OUTTA YR l
OIC

KTHXBYE
```

Comment: 1. Which interpreter are you using? 2. Can you `MAEK n A NUMBR` to cast? 3. Can you use `DIFFRINT` instead of `BOTH SAEM` and switch the conditionals?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I was using LOLCOFFEE, the one on repl.it. (Which appears to be down at the moment, so I'll test your suggestions once it's back up.)

Comment: Doesn't `O RLY?` cast to boolean?

Comment: @LeakyNun No...? `O RLY?` is like a postfix `if`.

Answer (score 15):

## [Bitwise Cyclic Tag](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag), 3 bits or < 1 byte

Bitwise Cyclic Tag is one of the simplest Turing-complete languages out there. It works with two bitstrings, the *program* and the *data*. The bits of the *program* are read cyclically and interpreted as follows:

- `0`: Delete the first data bit (and output it, in implementations that have output).
- `1x`: If the first data bit is `1`, append `x` (representing either `0` or `1`) to the end of the data. (If the first data bit is `0`, do nothing.)

The program runs until the data string is empty.

#### Truth-machine

```
110
```

When the data string is set to `0`:

- `11` does not append anything because the first data bit is not `1`.
- `0` deletes/outputs `0`.
- The data string is now empty and the program halts.

When the data string is set to `1`:

- `11` appends a `1`.
- `0` deletes/outputs `1`.
- The data string is back to a single `1` and the program is back to where it started, so we loop forever.

Answer (score 13):

### [Labyrinth](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Labyrinth), 7 bytes

```
 ?+
@!:
```

Labyrinth is a 2D stack-based language where control flow depends on the sign of the top element of the stack, checked after every instruction. Execution begins moving rightward from the first valid instruction on the top row, which here is the `?`.

The relevant instructions are:

```
?      Input integer
+      Add top two elements (Labyrinth's stack has infinite 0s on the bottom)
:      Duplicate top element
!      Output as number
@      Terminate program
```

If the input is 0, the IP reads input with `?`, adds the top two of the stack (`0 + 0 = 0`), then duplicates `:` and outputs `!` a 0. Here we encounter the sole junction in the program, and have to check the top of the stack to determine where to go. Since the top is 0, we move forward and terminate with `@`.

On the other hand, if the input is 1, we do the same instruction as before (but outputting a 1) before reaching the junction at the `!`. Now the top of the stack is positive, causing us to turn right into the `?`. On EOF Labyrinth pushes 0, so we do `0 + 1 = 1` at the `+`, duplicate `:`, and output `!`. Once again we have a 1 at the top of the stack and the loop continues.

For a bonus, here's @MartinBüttner's 7 byte solution, which operates similarly:

```
?+!@
1!
```

Note that, unlike most languages, `1` actually pops `n` off the stack and pushes `n*10 + 1`, making the building up of large numbers easy. However, since the top of the stack is empty at that point, it's no different from merely pushing 1.

Answer (score 13):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 7 bytes

```
i2%:n:,
```

This uses the fact that ><> pushes -1 on EOF, which is 1 mod 2. It also uses divide by 0 for termination (which is apparently okay since the consensus is that STDERR output is ignored).

Just for reference, exiting cleanly without errors is an extra byte:

```
i2%:n?!;
```

Comment: [`i2%:n?`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9NI1SrP/v9/AwA). With input on the stack like the other answers, this could be just [`:?:n`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38reKu////@6ZQYA)

Answer (score 13):

### C, 37 bytes

A different take on how to do it in C.

```
main(c){for(gets(&c);putchar(c)&1;);}
```

`c` defaults to an `int` of value 1. `gets(&c)` gets a string from `stdin`, here clobbering the value of `c`, hackishly since `c` is not a `char*`. `putchar(c)` prints the value of `c` to `stdout`, and returns `c`. Since `'0'` is 48 and `'1'` is 49 in ASCII, we can use the last bit (`&1`) to determine which it is. If it's `'0'`, the loop breaks. Otherwise, it goes forever.

Compiles (with a warning about `gets`) and runs under `gcc-4.8` on Linux.

Comment: Presumably this only works on little-endian architectures.

Comment: @Neil I would assume so.

Comment: @Neil Endianness only affects byte order in multibyte values.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 `c` defaults to an `int`, which is a multibyte value, and on a big-endian architecture, `gets` will set the wrong byte.

Answer (score 11):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 6 bytes

```
::n?!;
```

Pushes the input on the stack to start

```
:        copy top element on stack
 :       copy top element on stack again
  n      pop and outputs top element
   ?     condition trampoline - pops top element, if it is zero skips next instruction
    !    trampoline skips next instruction
     ;   finish execution
```

Comment: Here at PPCG, we love our explanations. +1

Comment: I'm pretty sure this only works with literal 0 and 1 inputs, when it's supposed to work with 48 (`'0'`) and 49 (`'1'`). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @quartata If it was me I'd say that, to be fair to any answers that use from more traditional methods of getting input, you should have to put 48 or 49 on the stack. It's your challenge though and it's not a huge deal anyway so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There's another problem with this: if the stack is pre-populated, then you have to add 3 bytes for the `-v` flag.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman It's 3 bytes now? I have seen 1 byte, and usually use 2 bytes. Is there a rule somewhere for this? Anyway I agree taking input directly on the stack isn't natural for ><> and should be mentionned.

Comment: @Aaron [This answer contains the only consensus we have on counting flags.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions/274#274) By that, it's 3 bytes.

Comment: @MartinBüttner thanks for the feedback ! However, I'm unsure where the value comes from, maybe are you counting the required space after `-v ` ? I'm referring to the "options to request different behaviors from the interpreter" section.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, exactly. It's only one byte, if you can combine it with some standard flag anyway, e.g. in the case of perl `perl -pe "perl code here"` where you'd need `-e` and the space anyway.

Comment: @MartinBüttner ok, it seems fair indeed, I'll make sure to use the correct value in future answers and will try to fix my older answers.

Comment: @Aaron: For what it's worth, I too thought it was 2 bytes for `-v`, then I was corrected. So you're not the only one. :)

Answer (score 11):

### APL, 6 bytes

```
→⎕←⍣⍲⎕
```

Explanation:

```
     ⎕ Read the input, then
 ⎕←    write it out
   ⍣   repeatedly
    ⍲  until NAND of it with itself becomes true.
→      Branch to zero to avoid printing the result again.
```

Comment: Are the second and the last characters supposed to look different? Because they don't for me.

Comment: @JanDvorak Nope, they're the same.

Comment: OK, now I'm looking at it on mobile and everything but the two arrows looks the same to me :-D

Answer (score 11):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/v1), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

<sub>[Crossed-out 4 is still 4 :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63755/rotate-the-anti-diagonals#comment153855_63756)</sub>

```
,W■
```

`,` reads a value from STDIN. `W` starts a loop that runs while the value on top of the stack is truthy, with the body `■`. `■` prints the top stack element without popping. The loop is implicitly closed at EOF.

On input of `0`, the loop never executes (since `0` is falsey), and the program ends at EOF, automatically popping and printing every value on the stack. On input of `1` (or any value that is not `0`, `""`, or `[]`), the loop runs infinitely.

In [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), the leading `,` is not needed (thanks to implicit input), bringing the score down to 2 bytes.

Answer (score 10):

## GNU sed, 10

```
:;/1/{p;b}
```

#### Explanation

- `:` define an unnamed label
- `/1/` If input matches the regex `1`, then
- `p` print the pattern space (i.e. 1)
- `b` and jump back to the unnamed label (forever)
- If the input was not 1 (i.e. 0), then the pattern space is printed unmodified and the program ends.

Comment: Shave 1 character off using `:;p;/1/b` and the _n_ flag, for a total of 9 bytes. Since `sed -f` is used anyway to run the script file, adding that extra flag doesn't require 2 bytes.

Answer (score 10):

### [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/mbuettner/brian-chuck), 21 bytes

```
,}<-{-?<SOH>_{+?
_>+{?<.p
```

Here, `<SOH>` should be replaced with the corresponding control character (0x01).

#### Explanation

The basic idea is to subtract the character code of the input (48 or 49) from the `p` at the end of Chuck, which will either give a `?` (which is a valid command) or a `@` which is a no-op.

`,` reads the input character into Chuck's first cell (marked with `_`). We want to decrement this value down to `0` in a loop, while making some other changes:

`}<` moves to the `p` and `-` decrements it. Then `{` moves back to the input cell `-` decrements that as well. As long as this isn't zero yet, `?` gives control to Chuck. Now `>` moves Brian's tape head one cell to the right (which is initialised to `1`) and `+` increments that. Then we reset the loop with `{?`.

By the time the first cell on Chuck hits `0`, the `<SOH>` cell will have been incremented to the character we've read from STDIN and `p` will be `?` for input `1` or `@` for input `0`.

Now `?` doesn't switch control any more. The `0` or `1` after it is a no-op, as is the null-byte (represented by `_`). `{` moves back to Chuck's first cell and `+` increments to ensure that it's positive, such that `?` hands control over to Chuck.

This time `>+` increments the cell after the end of Brian's initial tape. That cell is garbage but we'll never use it. Now `{` doesn't scan all the way to the front of Brian's tape, but only to the `_`. Hence `?` is a no-op because the current cell is zero. Then `<.` moves one to the left (the copy of the input character) and prints it.

Finally, we encounter the `?` or `@`. If the input was `0` and this cell is `@` it's a no-op and the program terminates. But if the input was `1` and this cell is `?` we hand over to Brian whose `{+?` will reset the loop on Chuck, and now we're printing `1`s forever (until the integer in the cell at the end of Brian's tape doesn't fit into memory any more, I suppose...).

#### Bonus

Sp3000 and I have been golfing away at this for several days. We started out around 40 bytes and arrived at two completely different, but tied solutions at 26 bytes. Only when I started to write up the explanation for mine, did the 21-byte solution above occur to me. Many thanks to Sp for throwing ideas around and teaching each other some golfing tricks in B&C. :)

This is his 26 byte solution:

```
>,----{?{>1?0
#I<?_}<.<<<?
```

And this is mine:

```
,{>-<-?_0+?_1{<?
_®{?_{>.?
```

Where `®` is a byte with value 174 (e.g. just save the file as ISO 8859-1).

At the core mine works similarly to the 21-byte solution, in that `®` becomes `}` for input `1` and `~` (no-op) for input `0`, but the execution is much less elegant.

His solution is quite neat in that the source code is ASCII-only and that it doesn't require a loop to process the input. Instead, `----` turns `1` into `-` and `0` into `,` (a no-op for Chuck). That `-` will then change the first `?` on Brian's tape into a `>`, thereby creating different control flow for the `1`-case.

Answer (score 9):

## Thue, 34 bytes

```
1::=12
2::=~1
0::=~0
@::=:::
::=
@
```

**Explanation:**

`1::=12` Instances of the substring "1" can become "12"

`2::=~1` Instances of the substring "2" can be removed, printing "1"

`0::=~0` Instances of the substring "0" can be removed, printing "0"

`@::=:::` Instances of the substring "@" can be replaced with strings from the input

`::=`     End list of substitution rules

`@`       The initial string is "@"

Answer (score 9):

## Arnold C, 134 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i
YOU SET US UP 0         //or 1
STICK AROUND i
TALK TO THE HAND 1
CHILL
TALK TO THE HAND 0
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

While this isn't as entertaining as the other ArnoldC [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62777/39328), it's golfed. For example, indentation is unnecessary, and so are the macros `@NO PROBLEMO` and `@I LIED`.

Tested with [this version of the language](http://mapmeld.github.io/ArnoldC/), which cannot take input.

Answer (score 9):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 5 <s>6</s> bytes

Cubix is @ETHproductions new 2 dimensional language where the commands are wrapped around the faces of a cube. [Online interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix)
Thanks to @ETHproductions for the saving.

```
!I\@O
```

This ends up expanded out to the cube

```
  !
I \ @ O
  .
```

This starts with the `I` command.  Input an integer onto the stack.
`\`, redirects the instruction pointer down over the no op.
`O`, outputs the numeric value of top of stack.
`!`, skip the next command (`@`) if top of stack true.  This will jump the `\`  redirect if 1
`\`, redirects the instruction pointer to the `@` exit program.

This takes advantage of the fact the stack isn't popped by the `O ? !` commands.

Comment: Nice. I'm really glad to see someone else using my language :) I have another 6-byte solution that only uses 5 instructions (plus a no-op), so perhaps I'll post that.

Comment: @ETHproductions post it for sure.  I think you've got a promising language here :)

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the `?` and just using `!`: `!I\@O`

Comment: @ETHproductions very nice

Comment: I've written a [brute-forcer](https://jsfiddle.net/esnjamtg/1/) for this (warning: freezes your browser for a minute or two), which comes up with exactly five 5-byte solutions: `@IOw!`, `@I?Ov`, `@!IOw`, `!IOW@`, `!I\@O`

Answer (score 8):

### [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 6 bytes

```
&1($i)
```

Input is hardcoded as the second character, since Foo doesn't have STDIN input. Don't we agree that Foo is awesome now? :)

#### Explanation

```
&1          Set current cell to 1
  (  )      Do-while loop (or, at least according to the interpreter)
   $i       Print current cell as int
```

Comment: I always liked Foo.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, <s>18 + 1 = 19</s> 13 + 1 = 14 bytes

```
print while$_
```

Run like this:

```
echo -n NUM | perl -p truth.pl
```

Thanks to ThisSuitIsBlackNot (who is way better at Perl golfing than me) for golfing off five bytes.

Comment: Statement modifiers are your friend! Also, if you ensure that the input has no trailing newline, you can drop the `+0`: `echo -n 0 | perl -pe'print while$_'` (13 bytes + 1 for `-p`). `perl -M5.010 -pe'say while$_'` would be even shorter, but that results in inconsistent newlines between 0 vs. 1.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ah-ha! I tried print while$_ but I couldn't figure out why it didn't work. I didn't realize you couldn't have the trailing newline on the input.

Comment: Yep, the string `0` is false but `0` + newline is true. See [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood).

Comment: `say` is shorter, even if you count `-E` as an extra byte.

Comment: @Dennis As I mentioned in my first comment, `say` doesn't work for this because it leaves a newline after 1, but no newline after 0, which violates the rule that usage of newlines must be consistent.

Comment: @Dennis ...which I just realized can be fixed with `-l`: `perl -lpE 'say while$_'` (11 bytes + 2 for `-lp`).

Answer (score 7):

## [MarioLANG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
;:
[^
=:
```

This prints a *space* after each `0` or `1` (as has been clarified is acceptable). The program was tested in the Ruby interpreter. It's not clear whether this behaviour of `^` is according to spec, but it works consistently in this implementation.

As usual, `=` is just some ground for Mario to walk on.

- `;` reads an *integer* from STDIN into the current tape cell.
- `[` is a conditional. If the tape cell is `0`, Mario skips the next cell (the `^`), which will make him fall through the `:` (printing the `0`), off the bottom edge and terminate the program (poor Mario). If the tape cell is `1`, this does nothing, and execution continues.
- `^` is a jump command. It stops Mario from moving forward and sends him straight up one cell before he falls back down. For some reason (at least in this implementation) Mario can jump in mid-air provided there's another cell (even a space) below the jump. That means Mario repeatedly jumps into the top `:`, printing the `1`, falls back down onto the `^` and performs another jump. This must be a feature from the popular Super Ninja Brothers spin-off.

Comment: Aww, poor mario.

Answer (score 7):

## [PlatyPar](http://rawgit.com/cyoce/Par/master/page.html), 2 Bytes

```
wA
```

Explanation:

Implicit: push input to the stack.

`w`: while last item.
`A`: alert last item.

If you give it something truthy, `while(stack[-1])` goes on infinitely. If not, it skips that, and alerts the last item of the stack implicitly (falsy).

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/Par/master/page.html?code=wA)
Press `cancel` instead of `ok` on the alert if you want to stop the loop after giving a 1.

Comment: why `Platy`? Is it different from normal `Par`?

Comment: After extensive research, I failed to discover there was already a language named Par. I found this as someone had posted an answer in a language called Par (not mine), and I was getting credit for his answers, and vice-versa. I have renamed mine, as I am sure the other came first (mine is only a week old).

Answer (score 6):

### [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), <s>11</s> 7 bytes

Inspired by [Sp3000's ><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62789/16766).

```
r.*.n!(
```

Each line of code in an Ouroboros program represents a snake eating its tail.

`r` reads a number from input, or -1 for EOF. `.*` squares it, keeping 0 and 1 the same but mapping -1 to 1. `.n` outputs the number, leaving a copy on the stack. Finally, `!(` logically negates and  eats that many characters of the end of the snake. If the number was `0`, this eats one character, the `(`, which is also the current instruction. Since the instruction pointer was swallowed, the snake dies and the program ends. If the number was `1`, this eats zero characters, and execution loops back to the beginning of the snake, repeating indefinitely.

Try it:

```js
// Define Stack class
function Stack() {
  this.stack = [];
  this.length = 0;
}
Stack.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.stack.push(item);
  this.length++;
}
Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack.pop();
    this.length--;
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.top = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack[this.length - 1];
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "" + this.stack;
}

// Define Snake class
function Snake(code) {
  this.code = code;
  this.length = this.code.length;
  this.ip = 0;
  this.ownStack = new Stack();
  this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  this.alive = true;
  this.wait = 0;
  this.partialString = this.partialNumber = null;
}
Snake.prototype.step = function() {
  if (!this.alive) {
    return null;
  }
  if (this.wait > 0) {
    this.wait--;
    return null;
  }
  var instruction = this.code.charAt(this.ip);
  var output = null;
  console.log("Executing instruction " + instruction);
  if (this.partialString !== null) {
    // We're in the middle of a double-quoted string
    if (instruction == '"') {
      // Close the string and push its character codes in reverse order
      for (var i = this.partialString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currStack.push(this.partialString.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      this.partialString = null;
    } else {
      this.partialString += instruction;
    }
  } else if (instruction == '"') {
    this.partialString = "";
  } else if ("0" <= instruction && instruction <= "9") {
    if (this.partialNumber !== null) {
      this.partialNumber = this.partialNumber + instruction;  // NB: concatenation!
    } else {
      this.partialNumber = instruction;
    }
    next = this.code.charAt((this.ip + 1) % this.length);
    if (next < "0" || "9" < next) {
      // Next instruction is non-numeric, so end number and push it
      this.currStack.push(+this.partialNumber);
      this.partialNumber = null;
    }
  } else if ("a" <= instruction && instruction <= "f") {
    // a-f push numbers 10 through 15
    var value = instruction.charCodeAt(0) - 87;
    this.currStack.push(value);
  } else if (instruction == "$") {
    // Toggle the current stack
    if (this.currStack === this.ownStack) {
      this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
    } else {
      this.currStack = this.ownStack;
    }
  } else if (instruction == "s") {
    this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  } else if (instruction == "S") {
    this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
  } else if (instruction == "l") {
    this.currStack.push(this.ownStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == "L") {
    this.currStack.push(this.program.sharedStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == ".") {
    var item = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(item);
    this.currStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "m") {
    var item = this.ownStack.pop();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "M") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.pop();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "y") {
    var item = this.ownStack.top();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "Y") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.top();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "\\") {
    var top = this.currStack.pop();
    var next = this.currStack.pop()
    this.currStack.push(top);
    this.currStack.push(next);
  } else if (instruction == "@") {
    var c = this.currStack.pop();
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(c);
    this.currStack.push(a);
    this.currStack.push(b);
  } else if (instruction == ";") {
    this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "+") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a + b);
  } else if (instruction == "-") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a - b);
  } else if (instruction == "*") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a * b);
  } else if (instruction == "/") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a / b);
  } else if (instruction == "%") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a % b);
  } else if (instruction == "_") {
    this.currStack.push(-this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "I") {
    var value = this.currStack.pop();
    if (value < 0) {
      this.currStack.push(Math.ceil(value));
    } else {
      this.currStack.push(Math.floor(value));
    }
  } else if (instruction == ">") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a > b));
  } else if (instruction == "<") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a < b));
  } else if (instruction == "=") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a == b));
  } else if (instruction == "!") {
    this.currStack.push(+ !this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "?") {
    this.currStack.push(Math.random());
  } else if (instruction == "n") {
    output = "" + this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "o") {
    output = String.fromCharCode(this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "r") {
    var input = this.program.io.getNumber();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "i") {
    var input = this.program.io.getChar();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "(") {
    this.length -= Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.max(this.length, 0);
  } else if (instruction == ")") {
    this.length += Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.min(this.length, this.code.length);
  } else if (instruction == "w") {
    this.wait = this.currStack.pop();
  }
  // Any unrecognized character is a no-op
  if (this.ip >= this.length) {
    // We've swallowed the IP, so this snake dies
    this.alive = false;
    this.program.snakesLiving--;
  } else {
    // Increment IP and loop if appropriate
    this.ip = (this.ip + 1) % this.length;
  }
  return output;
}
Snake.prototype.getHighlightedCode = function() {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.code.length; i++) {
    if (i == this.length) {
      result += '<span class="swallowedCode">';
    }
    if (i == this.ip) {
      if (this.wait > 0) {
        result += '<span class="nextActiveToken">';
      } else {
        result += '<span class="activeToken">';
      }
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i)) + '</span>';
    } else {
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  if (this.length < this.code.length) {
    result += '</span>';
  }
  return result;
}

// Define Program class
function Program(source, speed, io) {
  this.sharedStack = new Stack();
  this.snakes = source.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(snakeCode) {
    var snake = new Snake(snakeCode);
    snake.program = this;
    snake.sharedStack = this.sharedStack;
    return snake;
  }.bind(this));
  this.snakesLiving = this.snakes.length;
  this.io = io;
  this.speed = speed || 10;
  this.halting = false;
}
Program.prototype.run = function() {
  this.step();
  if (this.snakesLiving) {
    this.timeout = window.setTimeout(this.run.bind(this), 1000 / this.speed);
  }
}
Program.prototype.step = function() {
   for (var s = 0; s < this.snakes.length; s++) {
    var output = this.snakes[s].step();
    if (output) {
      this.io.print(output);
    }
  }
  this.io.displaySource(this.snakes.map(function (snake) {
      return snake.getHighlightedCode();
    }).join("<br>"));
 }
Program.prototype.halt = function() {
  window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}

var ioFunctions = {
  print: function (item) {
    var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
    stdout.value += "" + item;
  },
  getChar: function () {
    if (inputData) {
      var inputChar = inputData[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
      result = inputChar.charCodeAt(0);
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  getNumber: function () {
    while (inputData && (inputData[0] < "0" || "9" < inputData[0])) {
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
    }
    if (inputData) {
      var inputNumber = inputData.match(/\d+/)[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(inputNumber.length);
      result = +inputNumber;
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  displaySource: function (formattedCode) {
    var sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display');
    sourceDisplay.innerHTML = formattedCode;
  }
};
var program = null;
var inputData = null;
function showEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "block";
  stdin.style.display = "block";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  
  source.focus();
}
function hideEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "none";
  stdin.style.display = "none";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  
  var sourceHeight = getComputedStyle(source).height,
    stdinHeight = getComputedStyle(stdin).height;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = sourceHeight;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = sourceHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = stdinHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = stdinHeight;
  sourceDisplay.textContent = source.value;
  stdinDisplay.textContent = stdin.value;
}
function escapeEntities(input) {
  return input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
function resetProgram() {
  var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
  stdout.value = null;
  if (program !== null) {
    program.halt();
  }
  program = null;
  inputData = null;
  showEditor();
}
function initProgram() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin');
  program = new Program(source.value, +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML, ioFunctions);
  hideEditor();
  inputData = stdin.value;
}
function runBtnClick() {
  if (program === null || program.snakesLiving == 0) {
    resetProgram();
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
    var stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second');
    program.speed = +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML;
  }
  program.run();
}
function stepBtnClick() {
  if (program === null) {
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
  }
  program.step();
}
function sourceDisplayClick() {
  resetProgram();
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.so-box {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    border: 1px solid #c47b07;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: #f88912;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
}
.control {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}
span[contenteditable] {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    background: #cc7801;
    color: #fff;
}
#stdout-container, #stdin-container {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
#reset {
    float: right;
}
#source-display-wrapper , #stdin-display-wrapper{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#source-display , #stdin-display{
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 2px;
}
.activeToken {
    background: #f93;
}
.nextActiveToken {
    background: #bbb;
}
.swallowedCode{
    color: #999;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--
Designed and written 2015 by D. Loscutoff
Much of the HTML and CSS was taken from this Befunge interpreter by Ingo Bürk: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40331/16766
-->
<div class="container">
<textarea id="source" placeholder="Enter your program here" wrap="off">r.*.n!(</textarea>
<div id="source-display-wrapper" onclick="sourceDisplayClick()"><div id="source-display"></div></div></div><div id="stdin-container" class="container">
<textarea id="stdin" placeholder="Input" wrap="off">1</textarea>
<div id="stdin-display-wrapper" onclick="stdinDisplayClick()"><div id="stdin-display"></div></div></div><div id="controls-container" class="container clearfix"><input type="button" id="run" class="control so-box" value="Run" onclick="runBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="pause" class="control so-box" value="Pause" onclick="program.halt()" /><input type="button" id="step" class="control so-box" value="Step" onclick="stepBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="reset" class="control so-box" value="Reset" onclick="resetProgram()" /></div><div id="stdout-container" class="container"><textarea id="stdout" placeholder="Output" wrap="off" readonly></textarea></div><div id="options-container" class="container"><div class="option so-box">Steps per Second:
<span id="steps-per-second" contenteditable>20</span></div></div>
```

---

Previous two-snake solution:

```
rm1(
S.n.!(
```

**Snake 1**

`r` reads a number from input; `m` moves it to the shared stack. Then `1(` causes the snake to eat its instruction pointer and die.

**Snake 2**

`S` switches to the shared stack. `.n` duplicates the value and outputs it as a number. `.!(` duplicates again, logically negates, and eats that many characters. If the number was `0`, this eats one character, killing the second snake and ending the program. If the number was `1`, this eats zero characters and execution loops back to the beginning of the snake, repeating indefinitely.

Comment: Did you just post the source code for an interpreter with the answer? Why not link to it?

Comment: @Cyoce The interpreter was written as part of Helka Homba's stack snippet challenge. Per his own statement, "the point is to make something that can be easily copied and used in future PPCG questions and answers." The fact that it was done here means that Helka's plan worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Acc!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62404) - <s>54 50 48</s> 49 Bytes

```
N
Write _
Count q while _-48 {
Write _
}
```

Comment: Works in *[Acc!!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766)* too! ;)

Answer (score 6):

## AutoHotkey, 20 bytes

I recently got into AutoHotkey and have been waiting for a suitable challenge to try my skills at.

```
$0::Send 0
1::Send
```

This takes input by listening for key presses and outputs via simulated key presses. The `$` on the first line forces the first hotkey to take input through the keyboard only, so it just outputs `0` when the <kbd>0</kbd> key is pressed. The second is not so lucky though. When it detects the <kbd>1</kbd> key being pressed, it presses the <kbd>1</kbd> key, which it detects, so it presses <kbd>1</kbd>, which it detects and so on. AutoHotkey unfortunately doesn't like this, but that can probably be fixed by adding `#HotkeysInterval 1` to the top of the program. I am not brave enough to try this though, as it will probably crash my computer.

If input and output through key presses is invalid, here's a solution that avoids it:

```
InputBox, a
MsgBox %a%
While a{
MsgBox 1
}
```

Comment: This is the first answer I've seen in AutoHotkey. Have a +1

Answer (score 6):

## [Woefully](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Woefully), 266 bytes

First answer in this language!

It's called woefully because the bytecounts are saddening

Woefully is a 2d language with no conditionals, except for the notz/bool command (pop a, push 1 if not zero, else push zero), and combining this with the move char pointer command yields control flow. In a truth machine, the values entered are already zero or one, and are only of two values, so is less complex than some other conditional programs, which kind of defeats the purpose of the truth machine :P

There are two pointers, the instruction pointer (ip), and the char pointer (cp), and it's hard to explain in one post, but the ip goes through the paths, cp stays stationary unless moved by instructions the ip executes.

Woefully has 2 stacks, all pushing is to A, except dupe and AtoB

```
| || ||||| |
|| |||||| |
||| |||| |
|||| || |
||||| || |
||||| ||| |
||||| |||| |
||||| ||||| |
||||| |||||| |
||||| |
|||||| |
||||||| |
|||||| |
||||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
|| |
||| |
||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
|| |
||| |
|||| |
||||| |
|||||| |
```

[Try it online!](http://woefully.tryitonline.net/#code=fCB8fCB8fHx8fCB8Cnx8IHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fCB8fHx8IHwKfHx8fCB8fCB8Cnx8fHx8IHx8IHwKfHx8fHwgfHx8IHwKfHx8fHwgfHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8IHx8fHx8IHwKfHx8fHwgfHx8fHx8IHwKfHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8IHwKfHx8fHx8IHwKfHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8IHwKfHx8IHwKfHwgfAp8IHwKfHwgfAp8fHwgfAp8fHwgfAp8fHx8IHwKfHx8IHwKfHwgfAp8IHwKfCB8CnwgfAp8IHwKfCB8Cnx8IHwKfHx8IHwKfHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8IHwKfHx8fHx8IHw&input=MA)

Explanation (difficult from the size) Execution starts at the v, at the A path:

```
V   FI    \/  V shows initial char pointer pos, F the pos after movement
|A||X|||||Z|   if input is zero, I if it is 1. The path marked by \/ won't
||A||||||Z|    be executed until the first part has been done, and then only
|||A||||Z|  #X path halts program                          if input is zero 
||||A||Z|   # A path pushes input     #Z path pushes one
|||||A||O|
|||||E|||O|
|||||E||||O|   #E path dupes, by peeking top of a stack, pushing to b stack
|||||E|||||O| #O path outputs TOS of A
|||||E||||||O|
|||||E|    ^End of path, go back to char pointer, still over this path
||||||F|      #F path pops a, moves the char pointer
|||||||F|
||||||G|
|||||G|
||||G|
|||G|      #G path pushes 4
||G|
|G|
||H|   #H pops a, moves char pointer by a. the char pointer is (again)
|||H|  #now over F or I, depending on input
|||X|  X are nops
||||X|
|||L|   L path pushes 1
||L|
|L|
|V| V path multiplies both TOS (A and B), pushes to A
|V|
|V|
|V|
||O|
|||O|    O path outputs tos of A
||||O|
|||||O|
||||||O|
End of path, go back to the char pointer. If input was zero, the char
pointer will be over the halting path, so program over, otherwise it's over
the next char, and goes to the infinite one river
```

Note this is *somewhat* simplified: paths overlap on the corners they meet at.

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), <s>166</s> <s>156</s> <s>131</s> 123 bytes

Saved 10 bytes thanks to Pavel! Saved <s>25</s> 33 bytes thanks to Khuldraeseth na'Barya!

```
   ^       ^
  / \     / \
 /set\   /do \
^-----^ ^-----^
-    ^- -^   / \
    /l\ /#\ /out\
   /ine\---^-----
   -----   -
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtRCoAwDEP/d4qA36V4n1EQN3CgTtz88PRzrRooLwnpcZ/TlgKVeYlbbA2A4JU4gOHNdzpwiVUjh9yjkErw0ZH9EEj@vXL14KFfvqo1nPbodW9f2phRtjY@)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtNCoAgEIX3nuJB62HoPiJEDhRkRtqi05s6Lvo272fmXe@9hN1TWjcJUgoAh4EzAMNqqMaAk@Se2ceaHTXq/zCG@u2waKVOmu6nWJ4sOD5ZKxro0OAHlTJ/)

### Old answer and explanation (functionally equivalent)

```
    ^        ^
   / \      / \
  /set\    /do \
 ^-----^  ^-----^
/a\   /#\/a\   / \
---  ^------  /out\
    /l\      ^-----
   /ine\    /a\
   -----    ---
```

Hehe. I love this language.

### Explanation

There are two pyramid chains. The first is:

```
    ^
   / \
  /set\
 ^-----^
/a\   /#\
---  ^---
    /l\
   /ine\
   -----
```

This `set`s variable `a` to `line` (a line read from STDIN), as a value (`#`).

The second:

```
    ^
   / \
  /do \
 ^-----^
/a\   / \
---  /out\
    ^-----
   /a\
   ---
```

This is a `do while` loop, with the left pyramid being the condition, and the right one being the body. Equivalent to:

```
do {
    out(a);
} while(a);
```

which is what we want.

Comment: You could make the `line` pyramid one size smaller right? Since it ignores if its broken up with line breaks?

Comment: @Pavel Yes, that's true

Comment: @ETHproductions okay, will do!

Comment: @ETHproductions Added explanation!

Comment: Using the sneaky nameless variable gets you down to [131](https://tio.run/##TYtNCoAgEIX3nuJB62E6kAiRAwWZkbbo9KaOi77N@5l513svYfeU1k2ClALAYeAMwLAaqjHgJLln9rFmR436P4yhfjssWqmTpvsplicLjk/WigY6NPhBpcwf)

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya I'm impressed! Thanks!

Comment: [More savings :)](https://tio.run/##NYtRCoAwDEP/d4qA36V4n1EQN3CgTtz88PRzrRooLwnpcZ/TlgKVeYlbbA2A4JU4gOHNdzpwiVUjh9yjkErw0ZH9EEj@vXL14KFfvqo1nPbodW9f2phRtjY@)

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya That pyramid-chaining technique is really something!

Comment: Hehe. I also love this language.

Comment: I'm glad you enjoy it :D @Khuldraesethna'Barya

Answer (score 5):

## Groovy, <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```
x=System.in.text as int;while(x)print x;print x
```

Radical.

Comment: That is _nice_ how you're using the input. +1

Comment: Does Groovy have a do-while? IE `do print x;while(x);` (maybe needs braces)

Comment: @Justin No it doesn't sadly.

Comment: Funny that they don't list that in their [list of major differences between Groovy and Java](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html). I'd imagine this is a major difference.

Comment: you can save two bytes by not casting the input and doing an equality check to the string "1" - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/groovy#@19hG1xZXJKaq5eZp1eSWlHCVZ6RmZOqUWFrq2SopFlQlJlXolDBBaX//zcEAA "Groovy – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 5):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), <s>10</s> <s>5</s> 4 Bytes

New Versions! :D

```
[DN]
[  ]    Repeat while the top item is not 0
 D      Duplicate the top item
  N     Print it out.
```

<s>I would put a try it online link here, but [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy)'s try it online doesn't output every line as it is output yet.</s>

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=W0ROXQ&input=&args=MQ)

Comment: That's quite a golf... is input initially laid in the stack?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Turns out I was a version ahead - forgot to push my changes - in any case, I'll add the flag as part of the byte count.

Comment: You forgot to _push_ your changes? (Bad stack-related pun)

Comment: ...ಠ_ಠ​​​​​​​​​

Comment: The TIO link is broken :/

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```
x=prompt();do{alert(x)}while(+x)
```

On input of `0`, alerts `0` to the user; on input of `1`, forever alerts `1`. If `alert` is not a suitable alternative for STDOUT, replace it with `console.log` and add 6 to the byte count.

**Edit:** I've been solidly beat by @intrepidcoder; see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62831).

Answer (score 5):

## Simplex v.0.8, 3 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/#code=acKmbw)

```
i¦o
i   ~~ take input
 ¦  ~~ repeat next character until zero byte met
  o ~~ output character
```

Answer (score 5):

## C, 39

```
main(){for(;putchar(getchar()&49)&1;);}
```

STDIN must be a 1-byte file. It will not work if there is a trailing newline. This is because the program relies on all calls to `getchar` following a `1` to return EOF, which is represented as -1 (all ones in binary).

Answer (score 5):

## QBasic, 23 bytes

```
INPUT x
1?x
IF x THEN 1
```

Gotos are the best way to loop. ;^) `1` is a label; `?` is a shortcut for `PRINT`.

Comment: `GOTO`s are truely superior =D

Answer (score 5):

## Java, <s>149</s> <s>128</s> 120 bytes

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int n=System.in.read()%2;do System.out.print(n);while(n>0);}}
```

Why 120 bytes? Because Java.

Edit: Saved 21 bytes thanks to [Justin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9498/justin). Saved 8 bytes thanks to [dohaqatar7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31441/dohaqatar7).

Comment: See: [Java](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/44713)

Comment: `Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);int n=s.nextInt();` can be instead `int n=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();`. At that point, get rid of the import and do `int n=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();` Leaves you with 128 chars

Comment: There's no need to use a scanner, just read from `System.in` directly. `class A{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int n=System.in.read()%2;do System.out.print(n);while(n>0);}}` . You have to throw an Exception but it's shorter than all the crap with Scanner.

Comment: you could drop few charactrs if you use `for(;;)` loop instead `do while`

Comment: @user902383 Actually no, because then it would print 0's indefinitely too.  As it stands, it prints the 0 once, and 1 indefinitely, just as it should.

Answer (score 5):

## [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 6 bytes

Prelude is a bit tricky here. [The language specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20060504072859/http://z3.ca/%7Elament/prelude.txt) says I/O is via characters' byte values. [That's what the C implementation does.](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/prelude/impl/prelude.c) Then there's [the Python interpreter](http://web.archive.org/web/20060504072747/http://z3.ca/%7Elament/prelude.py), which uses bytes for input but prints decimal integers. And then there's [my own fork of that interpreter](https://gist.github.com/m-ender/5f5688758c7171a6675c) which does both input and output numerically (which I've published a few months ago). Since languages on PPCG are defined by their implementations, all of these constitute valid Prelude variants.

My fork gives the shortest solution at 6 bytes:

```
?(1!)!
```

`?` pushes the input. `(...)` is a Brainfuck-style while loop, which is skipped for `0` input. Then `!` prints the zero. If the input was `1`, we enter the loop, push another `1` and print that with `!` (we need to push a new `1`, because `!` pops the top of the stack).

Next up is the original Python interpreter at **14 bytes**:

```
?6^+^+^+-(1!)!
```

Since output is the same as in my fork, all we need to do is map the character codes to `0` or `1` which we do by subtracting `48`. There are several ways to get `48` in 7 bytes, but I don't think it's possible to do it in less. This one pushes `6` and then doubles it 3 times, by duplicating it with `^` and adding the two copies with `+`.

Finally, the solution that works with the original C interpreter needs **16 bytes**:

```
?^(#^!^6^+^+^+-)
```

This one has a slightly different structure. Since we also need to output `48` or `49` respectively, we now remember the input and obtain the `0` or `1` only for the loop condition. This also let's us get a way with a single `!` because we can easily turn the loop into do-while. Again, `?` reads the input and `^` makes a copy which we only need because the first thing in the loop is `#`, which discards the top of the stack (we need this to discard the condition from a previous iteration). Now `^!` prints a copy of the input. Then `^6^+^+^+-` computes `input - 48` as before. If that is `0`, we leave the loop immediately and exit after printing a single number. Otherwise, the loop will keep going, printing the input `49` each time.

Comment: By "fork" do you mean you toggled the option on that one line?

Comment: @feersum I added it.

Comment: I was thinking of the NUMERIC_OUTPUT on line 5, but forgot it only affects one of I/O. I guess you had to add a numeric input option too for your modification.

Comment: @feersum yeah, exactly. The original Prelude interpreter already has the output flag set.

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
/1/+>G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X99QX9vOPeH/fwMA)

#### Explanation

The stage `` G` `` itself is really a no-op (it's a Grep stage with an empty regex, which always matches). So it's all in the configuration. `>` prints the result of this stage (which is just the input) and `/1/+` wraps it in a loop which runs as long as the string contains a `1`. There's also implicit output at the end of the program. So we go through these two possibilities:

- If the input is `0`, the `/1/` condition fails, so the loop is never run. Instead, the program terminates, and the `0` is printed at the end.
- If the input is `1`, the `/1/` condition matches, so the loop gets executed. The loop iteration itself does nothing but print that `1`, so the string's value won't change and the loop will continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 5):

## Whitespace, <s>46</s> 37 bytes

Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for golfing 1 byte off the first instruction, and 8 bytes by removing the last 2 instructions, which makes the program jumps to non-existent label and terminates with error but still output correctly in the output stream.

```
SS SL  # push 0
SLS    # dup
TLTT   # readn
TTT    # load
LSS L  # label L
SLS    #   dup
SLS    #   dup
TLST   #   prtn
LTS TL #   jmpz TL
LSL L  # jmp L
```

[**Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/Eedics)

Previous safe version of the program which terminates normally has a proper label and the standard triple new line to end the program:

```
LSS TL # label TL
LLL    # end
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/Su6YOX)

Notation explanation:

- `#` starts comment
- `L` is newline
- `S` is space
- `T` is tab

I used this [interpreter](http://naokikp.github.io/wsi/whitespace.html) to develop the program and generate the comments.

Didn't expect the code to be this long. Whitespace requires the input to be read into heap, heap instructions consumes stack, printing instruction consumes the stack and even jump instruction consumes the stack, so it bloats the code with all the "duplicate top stack" instructions.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my answer that warrants a downvote?

Comment: On [this interpreter](https://whitespace.kauaveel.ee/), SSL is a valid way to push 0 (which makes it as efficient as the duplicate instruction, heh). Also, LLL doesn't seem to be required to end execution there if it hits end-of-file. That would bring it down to 41 bytes.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can golf some parts: `SS SSL` (push 0) can be `SS SL`. After specifying it's positive with `S` (or negative with `T`), it's already implicit 0, so no need for an additional `S` for 0. In addition, you can remove the trailing `LSSTL LLL`. It will exit with an error (Undefined Label) for input `0`, but that's [allowed according to the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/52210). [Try it online](https://tinyurl.com/ya3csbup), or [try it online raw **37 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y8d694on).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Updated.

Answer (score 5):

### LaTeX, 97 bytes

```latex
\documentclass{proc}\begin{document}\typein[\q]{}\loop\typeout{\q}\ifnum\q=1\repeat\end{document}
```

I guess it's sort of a grey area since everything is generated at compile time. Prints 1s to "`stdout`" until it runs out of memory or one 0 depending on input.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge-98, 7 bytes

```
&:.:j@#
```

Explanation:

```
&            Read integer
 :           Push copy
  .          Print the copy
   :         Push another copy
    j        Jump that many characters to the right
     q       Terminate program (jumped over if input was 1)
      #      Skip next instruction
             (And implicitly loop back to the start)
```

Answer (score 5):

### [ResPlicate](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ResPlicate), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
0 -49 12 1 48 9 0 49 4 2 0 49 4 2 48 0
```

<s>This was one of the earliest examples I made after implementing this language, so I have simply copied it from the linked wiki article, which I largely wrote.</s> Actually, having rewritten my old version to shorten it by a byte, I can now say this example was written for this catalogue.

#### ResPlicate in a Nutshell

Programs in ResPlicate are all comprised of a list of integers, which are inserted into a queue in order. Each step, the first two integers are popped as x and y. Then a list of x integers is popped (and padded with zeros if the queue had fewer than x elements) and re-enqueued y times. This is quite sufficient to ensure Turing-completeness. Indeed, it is even Turing-complete in the limited case that y is not allowed to exceed 2.

This simple language is extended with I/O in the following way: If x is zero and y is positive, y is output as a character. If x is zero and y is negative, a character is read from input, y+1 is added to it, and the result is enqueued.

#### Ungolfed:

Thus, the above program can be read like this:

```
0 -49                       Read a character from input, subtract 48 from its value.
                            If the input was 1 or 0, this will cause the corresponding 
                            integer value to be pushed onto the queue.
12 1 [48 9 ... 48 0]        Move the next 12 integers to the end of the queue. 
                            This brings the input integer to the front of the queue.
```

So now execution follows two completely different paths depending on the value of the input. If it was "0", it continues like this:

```
(0) 48                      The input zero and "48" are popped, causing the character
                            with value 48 ("0") to be printed.
9 0 [49 4 2 0 49 4 2 48 0]  Pop and discard the next 9 integers, emptying the queue.
                            An empty queue terminates the program.
```

If the input was "1", the program continues thusly:

```
(1) 48 [9]                  Enqueue 48 times the number 9.
0 [49]                      Print the character with value 49 ("1").
4 2 [0 49 4 2]              Place "0 49" (print "1") at the end of the queue,
                            followed by a copy of this command.
48 0 [9 9 ... 9 9]          Discard the 48 9's that were enqueued earlier.
```

At this point, the queue contains only "0 49 4 2 0 49 4 2", which will repeatedly print "1" and then restore the queue to precisely this state, ensuring that it will continue in this manner forever.

Answer (score 5):

### Marbelous, 22 bytes

```
00 .. ..
]] // ..
-O @1 ..
=O .. ..
+O /\ @1
```

All padding is superfluous in this program, spaces and dots can be removed.

The // sends the 00 marble through the ]] stdin device until there's a byte available, then it drops that byte. -O-O=0 or -O=O check for ascii 48 which is "0", then either the input gets output once or forever (through the @1 loop), incremented back up to the proper ascii value with a +O on the way out.

Answer (score 5):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), <del>13</del> <del>11</del> 8 chars

I could golf the solution down by 3 more bytes. This solution is pretty much a literal translation of my [Cardinal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68749/39407) solution:

```
_T> "{'j
```

Explanation:

```
_         generate bee/IP
 T        enter integer, set lstack top value to this value
  >       redirect bee to right              
    "     if lstack top value>0, skip next instruction
     {    output lstack top value to STDOUT
      '   if lstack top value=0, skip next instruction
       j  mirror bee direction along | axis
```

If `0` is entered, the following instructions get executed:

```
     +———————————————————————————— output '0'
     ↓
_T> "{'

After execution of ' the IP leaves the honeycomb and the program terminates.
```

And in case of entering `1`:

```
      +——————————————————————————— mirror bee direction of movement (to the left)
      | +————————————————————————— output '1'
      | |  +—————————————————————— redirect bee to the right
      | |  |   +—————————————————— mirror bee direction of movement
      | |  |   | +———————————————— output '1'
      | |  |   | |  +————————————— redirect bee to the right
      ↓ ↓  ↓   ↓ ↓  ↓
_T> "'j'{" > "'j'{" > .......      

... bouncing back and forth between > and j forever, printing an infinite string of ones.
```

Clone my beeswax interpreter (written in Julia), language specification and examples from [my GitHub repository](https://www.github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl).

Answer (score 5):

## [TrumpScript](https://github.com/JJ-Atkinson/TrumpScript), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
Say i
As long as,i is "1"?;:
Say i!
America is great.
```

The longer version:

```
Tell them what TrumpSaid
As long as , Cruz i is not number "1"?; :
Say what TrumpSaid !
America is great.
```

Comment: "Just think of debugging as a fun little game." lol

Comment: Just so you know this is a fork of the original TrumpScript for PPCG. https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge-93+, 7

```
&>:.:_@
```

`&` takes integer input. `:.:` is a palindromic loop: it duplicates the top of the stack, prints it, and duplicates it again. `_` will exit the the loop by moving to the right if the top of the stack is 0. Otherwise it executes the loop again, then `>` executes the loop again, and so on until the stack overflows. `@` terminates the program.

Answer (score 5):

## [JAISBaL](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL), <s>15</s> 6 bytes

```
˗Y1˄N0
```

Explanation:

```
# \# enable verbose parsing #\
while               \# [0] start while loop #\
    printnumln 1    \# [1] print 1 #\
end                 \# [2] end current language construct #\
printnum 0          \# [3] print 0 #\
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 2 bytes

```
V0
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IG51bWluCnNldCBudW1vdXQKCmdldApub3AKICAgIHB1dA&input=MA) Check *Debug* to see the generated binary code.

#### How it works

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

```lisp
set numin  ; Switch to numeric input.
set numout ; Switch to numeric output.

get        ; Read an integer from STDIN and save in in the current cell.
nop        ; Set an entry marker.
    put    ; Print the integer in the current cell.
           ; (implicit jnz)
           ;     If the integer in the current cell is non-zero,
           ;     jump to the previous instruction.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Forte](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Forte), <s>49</s> 60 bytes

```
3LET5=5+(0*4)
4INPUT0:LET6=6-(0*4)
5PRINT0:LET3=3+(0*4)
6END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/forte#@2/s4xpiamuqrWGgZaLJZeLpFxAaYmAFFDSzNdOFCJoGBHn6QQSNbY2hKs1c/Vz@/zcEAA)

Forte is a weird and wonderful language with BASIC-like syntax and an execution model based on redefining integers. It has no conditional or looping constructs; to get conditional or looping behavior, you have to redefine the line numbers your program uses.

#### How?

Here's the code with better spacing:

```
3 LET 5=5+(0*4)
4 INPUT 0 : LET 6=6-(0*4)
5 PRINT 0 : LET 3=3+(0*4)
6 END
```

If the user inputs a zero to this program, the three `LET` statements don't change anything, and the program boils down to `PRINT 0 : END`.

If the user inputs a one... it gets interesting.

```
3 LET 5=5+(0*4)
```

The first time around, no numbers have been redefined yet; this line calculates `5+(0*4)` and assigns that to `5`. Nothing changes.

```
4 INPUT 0 : LET 6=6-(0*4)
```

`INPUT 0` reads a number from the user and redefines `0` as that number. Suppose the user enters a `1`. Every time `0`, or a value of zero, occurs from now on, it will be changed to `1`. For instance: `LET 6=6-(0*4)` now is calculated as `LET 6=6-(1*4)`, which redefines `6` to be `2`. This changes the `END` statement's line number to `2`, which moves it out of the way of the program, allowing an infinite loop.

**Redefinitions:** `0->1; 6->2`

```
5 PRINT 0 : LET 3=3+(0*4)
```

First, this line prints `1` (the value that `0` now represents). Then, `0*4` is now `1*4`, so we have `LET 3=7`.

**Redefinitions:** `0->1; 6->2; 3->7`

Next, we increment the instruction pointer and execute the command on line <s>3</s> 7:

```
3 LET 5=5+(0*4)
```

which redefines `5` to be `5+4`...

**Redefinitions:** `0->1; 6->2; 3->7; 5->9`

... and we execute line <s>5</s> 9:

```
5 PRINT 0 : LET 3=3+(0*4)
```

which should be read (with substitutions) as `9 PRINT 1 : LET 7=7+(1*4)`. We print another `1` and change `7` to `11`, which means we execute the original line `3` again, and so forth.

For those who are still confused, read the [Esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Forte) or ping [ais523](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/246227/ais523) (the language's inventor!) in chat.

Answer (score 5):

### [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

*Thanks to Fatalize for saving 1 byte.*

```
w?1↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v9ze8FHbhv//DQA)

#### Explanation

```
w     Write the input to STDOUT.
 ?1   Check whether the input equals 1.
   ↰  If so, recursively call the main predicate with 1 again.
```

Comment: What a pity that `w`'s output isn't its input.

Answer (score 5):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), 10 bytes

```
."#:[#":1#
```

Yay for comment abuse in a normal challenge (instead of a source-layout or polyglot one)! In 1+, the `[` character that begins a comment is actually an instruction so it can be skipped with the goto command `#`.

For input 0:

```
.          Take input
 "#        Jump to the 0th hash tag
   ：      Output 0
    [      Comment the rest of the program out
```

For input 1:

```
.          Take input
 "#        Jump to the 1th hash tag
     #     The 1th hash tag
      ":   Duplicate and output
        1# Jump to the 1th hash tag
```

I can replace the `1` with `"` as well so that we get a 1+ program without a `1` instruction... Wow!

### Naive solution, 14 bytes

```
.1##":"1+1<1+#
```

A simple do-while loop.

Comment: @petStorm No, `[` is a block comment. It only comment everything else here because there's no `]`. Also why did I suddenly get 4 upvotes on tips for golfing in 1+?

Comment: I could remove the `[` because STDERR is ignored by default, but 1. This comment trick is really neat and 2. That's trivial

Answer (score 5):

### Google Forms, 3 sections + 1 question

[Try it online!](https://forms.gle/D1QXJZoiHY2tVzLw7)

Google Forms has two features which I believe make it qualify as a (very limited) programming language:

1. Multiple sections, which allow arbitrary rules for which sections redirect to which, allowing for uncontrolled infinite loops
2. The ability to make different responses to a question take the user to a different section upon clicking "next", allowing for input/conditionals, and controlling loops based on input

Google Forms also has a back button, which may make it possible to store arbitrarily large amounts of information, though there's no way to make use of that information without the human running the program doing something.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, 24 Bytes

```
param($a)do{$a}while($a)
```

Gets variable `$a`, then uses the `do-while` loop functionality to output `$a` at least once, but continuing the loop if `$a` is truthy (i.e., `1`).

---

Alternatively, using traditional while looping, also 24 bytes

```
param($a)while($a){$a}$a
```

In this instance, if `$a` is falsey, the `while` loop will never be executed and just the value of `$a` will be printed in the end statement. If `$a` is truthy, the program will enter the `while` loop and continuously print the value of `$a`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
ÿ ©ß
```

As of 25 Oct 2016, I have implemented the recursion feature `ß`, which calls the entire program as a function. This is used here like so:

```
      // Implicit: U = input integer
ÿ     // Since there's no value to work on, use U here. Alert U and return it.
  ©   // If U is truthy (1),
   ß  //   run the program again with the same inputs.
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=dev&code=/yCp3w==&input=MQ==)

Comment: Yay! We should hold competitions between Japt, , and Teascript to see which is the most effective JS-based lang.

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ That sounds great! But let's have at least another week to develop the langs; I've only worked on the Japt interpreter for ~8 hours and gotten ~2/3 of the features (all the easy ones) done. :-)

Comment: Sure! I could probably implement some improvements, too.

Comment: Just curious, is there a shorter way to do this in newer Japt versions?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc I've recently implemented the `ÿ` command, which alerts the value of an object and returns it, so I think `Uÿ ©ßU` should also work. I'll have to test it though.

Comment: @Flp.Tkc Actually, it can be `Uÿ ©ß` because `ß` implicitly uses the inputs as arguments. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-98, 16 bytes

```
&>:;#,1';#<_'0,@
```

Tested in pyfunge and BeQunge.

#### Simpler two-line version

```
&>:! |
@^,1']'0,
```

I like the previous one more, but this is what I came up with first.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on my Befunge skills, but `&:.jq>:.<` appears to work, and is 9 bytes.

Comment: @Mego Damn. :-P

Comment: Whoops, looks like I missed a char. `&::.jq>:.<` for 10.

Comment: As @ThomasKwa pointed out in chat, `&::.jq#` works and is 7.

Comment: @Mego I'm not going to steal that. I'll let the inventor(s) post it.

Comment: It's been [posted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63288/39328).

Answer (score 4):

### HP48's [RPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPL_%28programming_language%29), 22.5 bytes

```
« WHILE DUP REPEAT DUP END »
```

Since there is no such thing as STDIN or STDOUT on the HP48, the input is taken on the stack, and one "0" or an infinity of "1"s are pushed back on the stack.

If you try it, you will have to kill the program in order to see the "1"s since the stack is not refreshed while the program is running (Just press the "ON" button).

PS: The HP48's memory is made of 4 bits words, hence the non-integer bytes size

Answer (score 4):

## Prolog, 28 bytes

```
a(X):-write(X),X=0,!;a(X).
```

The cut `!` is necessary to terminate the execution in the interpreter, otherwise it will wait to see if the user wants to get other answers.

Comment: No need for the extra parentheses! Saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @mat `true.` Not sure what I was thinking!

Answer (score 4):

### [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 19 bytes

```
0 0 * * 1
0 * 1 r 0
```

Halts on 0 because there is no state 1.

Answer (score 4):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Shakespeare), 189 bytes

```
.
Ajax,.
Ford,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Ajax and Ford]
Ford:
Listen to thy heart.
Scene II:.
Ford:
Open thy heart.Is cat as big as you?If so, let us return to scene II.
[Exeunt]
```

Ungolfed:

```
The Construction of a Truth-Machine in Denmark.

Hamlet, the input.
Ophelia, who orders him around.

Act I: A truth-machine.

Scene I: In which Hamlet learns that all he needs, he can find in his heart.

[Enter Hamlet and Ophelia]

Ophelia:
  Listen to thy heart.

Scene II: In which Ophelia proclaims her doubts about Hamlet.

Ophelia:
  Open thy heart. Is my lover as fair as thee?
  If so, let us return to scene II.

[Exeunt]
```

I'm using [drsam94's SPL compiler](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl) + GCC to compile this.

To test:

```
$ python splc.py tm.spl > tm.c
$ gcc tm.c -o tm.exe
$ echo 0 | ./tm
0
$ echo 1 | ./tm
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...
```

Comment: Do you have the link for the Python implementation of SPL? looking to work on a JavaScript fork of it...

Comment: @WallyWest [Here it is!](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl)

Answer (score 4):

## [Deoxyribose](https://github.com/georgewatson/deoxyribose), 18 bytes

*Updated for the new v3 spec*

```
ATGGAGAAGAGCATAAAT
```

Explanation:

```
ATG                         ATA (*)
GAG Glu     Dupe            TGG Trp     Power
AAG Lys     Pop             AGA Arg     Unipop
AGC Ser     Jump if <= 0    AGA Arg     Unipop
ATA *                       GCA Ala     Modulo
AAT Asn     Loop            TAA End
```

- Execution starts at the initial ATG.
- The top element of the main stack is duplicated & printed, then
  If the value is less than or equal to zero, jump to the ATA formed by the Asn and the start codon (remember, the code is circular), then run through a series of no-ops, including printing some non-printable characters.
  If the value is greater than 0, loop back to the start.

If you don't like the ugly sequence of no-ops, adding ATG to the end to make the loop target explicit results in a clean termination immediately after the jump, for three more bytes.

---

**Deoxyribose 2, 21 bytes**

```
ATGTGAGAAAAATCTAACTTA
```

Explanation:

```
ATG Start                           TAA Stop ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┐
TGA Block size = 56               ┏ TGT Cys     Destination of Asn ┆
GAA Glu     Duplicate             ┃ GAG Glu     Duplicate          ┆
AAA Lys     Pop as int            ┃ AAA Lys     Pop as int         ┆
TCT Ser     If >= 0, jump to Thr ┐┞ AAT Asn     Jump back to Cys   ┆
AAC Asn     Jump back to Cys ────┼┘                                ┆
TTA                              └─ ACT Thr     Destination of Ser ┆
                                     └┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┘
```

---

This is the first challenge on this site ever answered in this language (since it's only a week old), but I think it's a good showcase of what the language can do so I'll provide a bit of an explanation of what's going on. If you happen to be really interested, the spec, a Python-based interpreter, and additional (less golfed) examples are [on GitHub](https://github.com/georgewatson/deoxyribose).

Deoxyribose is a stack-based language with a small instruction set and a syntax based on DNA.
Execution takes place on a circular stretch of DNA, translating 3-digit "codons" into proteins, each of which corresponds to either

- an operation on one or both of the stacks, or
- a (perhaps conditional) jump to a particular sequence elsewhere in the code.

These jumps can lead to frameshifts, where the read head is moved a non-integer number of codons and the same bit of code ends up doing two totally different things at different times. The degenerate nature of the genetic code makes it possible (and fun!) to use this to your advantage.

Comment: I love this language concept!

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck) (portable), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
>>>,.[[->+<<+>]>-]<+[<<]>[.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fzs5ORy86WtdO28ZG2y7WTjfWRjvaxibWLlov9v9/AwA)

(Improved by 1 byte thanks to Jo King, who found a terser way to start the `[<<]` loop.)

I know that on PPCG it's normally sufficient for an answer to work on one interpreter, but as this is a catalogue, I wanted a demonstration of a brainfuck answer that should work on any interpreter, and which exits without error on input `0`. This program makes no assumptions about cell size, EOF behaviour, wrapping, tape extension to the left, etc. It's the shortest brainfuck truth-machine I'm aware of with these properties.

### Explanation

```
>>>,.[[->+<<+>]>-]<+[<<]>[.]
>>>,                            Input a character to the fourth cell
    .                           Output that character
     [           ]              While the current cell is nonzero:
      [->+<<+>]                   Move the value to the next and previous cells
               >                  Make the next cell current
                -                 and decrement it
                  <+            Starting behind the current cell, at value 1
                    [<<]        Move back two cells at a time until we find zero
                        >[ ]    If the cell to the right is nonzero:
                          .       Output it forever
```

The basic idea here is to create a range on the tape, containing all values from the input's ASCII code down to 0. (So for example, if the input is `0`, we get 48 in the third cell, 47 in the fourth cell, 46 in the fifth cell, etc..) Once we've done that, we look at alternate values of the range until we end up at a tape element before the start of the range. If the range has an even length (i.e. the input has an even ASCII code), we'll end up two cells to the left of it, so moving to the right we'll end up in a cell we've never written to (and thus still has the value zero). If the range has an odd length, we'll end up only one cell to its left, so `>[.]` will move to the first cell of the range (i.e. the user input) and output it in a loop forever.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
for(;$args){1}0
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMNaJbEovViz2rDW4P///wYA)

**Edit:**
-1 byte thanks to @AdmBorkBork

Comment: Use a `for` loop to save a byte [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMNaJbEovViz2rDW4P///wYA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

### [PUBERTY](https://esolangs.org/wiki/PUBERTY), 369 bytes

```
It is May 1, 2018, 3:01:04 PM.Y is in his bed, bored.His secret kink is J.Soon the following sounds become audible.oh yeah yeah yeah hrg fap yeah yeah yeah fap yeah fap yeah yeah mmf yeah yeah yeah hrg yeah hrg fap yeah yeah yeah yeah fap yeah fap yeah mmf yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah yes yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah hrg fap yeah fap yeah fap yeah yeah yeah yeah mmf yeah mmf
```

**Ungolfed**

```
It is May 1, 2018, 3:01:04 PM.
Yhprum is in his bed, bored.
His secret kink is humaninteraction.
Soon the following sounds become audible.

oh yeah yeah yeah
hrg
    fap yeah yeah yeah fap yeah fap yeah yeah
mmf

yeah yeah yeah

hrg
    yeah
    hrg
       fap yeah yeah yeah yeah fap yeah fap yeah
    mmf
    yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah

    yes

    yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah
    hrg
        fap yeah fap yeah fap yeah yeah yeah yeah
    mmf
    yeah
mmf
```

This was very much harder than I expected it to be using this language.

**Explanation**

PUBERTY is a wonderful language. It has 6 registers (A, B, C, D, E, F) and one register pointer, all initialized to 0. At the end of each instruction, REGPTR %= 6 and REG[REGPTR] %= 256.

These are the commands used in this program:

- **oh** reads an ASCII character and stores its value into the current register
- **yeah** increments REGPTR by 1
- **hrg...mmf** loops until the current register has a value of zero
- **fap** increments the current register by 1
- **yes** prints the ASCII char corresponding to the value of the current register

The program starts with the header - the first four lines

```
It is May 1, 2018, 3:01:04 PM.
```

This sets $D to the Unix timestamp of the date % 256. In this case, we set it to 48. This statement is required

```
Yhprum is in his bed, bored.
```

This initializes $C to 6, the number of chars in the name, but we don't use this at all. This statement is required.

```
His secret kink is humaninteraction.
```

This line is where you declare all your kinks, if you want to learn about what they do, check out the esolang page since we don't use them here. This statement is required.

```
Soon the following sounds become audible.
```

Required line, does nothing.

```
oh yeah yeah yeah
hrg
    fap yeah yeah yeah fap yeah fap yeah yeah
mmf

yeah yeah yeah
```

read in a 0 or 1, then loop until $D is zero while incrementing $A and $B. This leaves us with $A containing ASCII value 0 or 1, depending on what was inputted and $B containing 208. Then move REGPTR back to A

```
hrg
    yeah
    hrg
       fap yeah yeah yeah yeah fap yeah fap yeah
    mmf
    yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah

    yes
```

In the inner loop, move REGPTR to $B (which  has the value 208) and loop until it is zero while incrementing $A and $F. This leaves us with $A containing 48 or 49 (the ASCII codes for 0 or 1) and F containing 48. Then print $A, which will output a 0 or 1 depending on which one was inputted.

```
    yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah
    hrg
        fap yeah fap yeah fap yeah yeah yeah yeah
    mmf
    yeah
mmf
```

Now we move REGPTR to $F and loop until that is zero while incrementing $A and $B. This leaves us with $A containing the ASCII value 0 or 1 and $B containing 208, just like it had at the start of the loop. The loop then exits if $A == 0 or loops infinitely if $A == 1.

This is my first codegolf answer so excuse any mistakes I made pls.

Answer (score 4):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `s`, 1 byte

The `s` flag forces a read from STDIN. This flag can be appended to the end of the command-line.

```
w
```

### No, I didn't just make a built-in for the question.

Here is the expanded program (because `w` requires two inputs)

```
aaw
```

This decodes into:

```
mywhile(a[0],'a[0]',a)
```

Which means:

```
while a[0]:
    print(a[0])
```

The print is implicit in every while iteration. Since `a[0]` is always `1` once it is defined as 1, this will print 1 forever (the body is the same as the condition).

So you might say that this prints nothing if the input is 0. You are wrong, the `w` instruction returns the condition `0` after the while statement is done. Therefore it gets returned and gets outputted.

### W `s`, 4 bytes

W was designed to be very powerful so that while loops are unneccecary. This program avoids this at the cost of being significantly longer. (Please don't use the while loop (which is simply for presentation purposes) in your W programs. Thank you.)

```
ibE&
```

### Explanation

```
   & % Perform logical AND between the input and the code block.
     % If the input is 1, execute the following code block:
i E  %     Count to infinity,
 b   %     Printing the input in every iteration
     % Otherwise (part of the AND logic):
     %     Return 0, exit the program.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <strike>123</strike> 120 bytes

(Whitespace added for readability)

```
T.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Puck]
Ajax:Listen tothy.Open heart.
     Am I worse you?If solet usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BCsIwEAV/5X1AWXruRXLoISAo6K30EOJK1ZqU7Ia2Xx8bbzMwMLLMpdzJvN3W0DX7T0PGK2xHN8@BKwz9xjnoOPRBOaGmcOGBWo/VuvNLlAM06rTTZTlwYpeUzBcWa0zC2GM@2SckzqzI8n9QKe0P)

I make use of a trick to reuse Scene I. For some reason, it doesn’t error to keep taking input, so I do that. Then I just compare the input to zero, and loop if it’s greater. Saved 3 bytes by comparing to I instead of zero because characters initialize to zero—thanks Robin Ryder!

Comment: You can use `Is I worse you?` instead of `Is zero worse you?`, since all characters are implicitly initialized at 0.

Comment: True true, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 28 bytes

```
func[a][until[prin a a = 0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OjE2ujSvJDMnuqAoM08hEQhtFQxiY/@nKRj8BwA)

Makes use of the fact that `until` will always execute its block at least once. The loop will only terminate if the argument passed to the function is 0, otherwise it will keep printing forever.

Comment: The loop will also terminate if you pass `0.0`, `0%`, `$0`, `#"^(null)"`, `0:0`, because it relies on the lax comparison. There's also `ask` for taking input from STDIN.

Comment: is there a consensus on how red/rebol function submissions should be made? this answer only seems to have the body.

Answer (score 4):

## [Flipbit](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Flipbit), 10 bytes

```
?>>>>>.[.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/394OBPSi9WL//zcAAA)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
def l(i):
 if i:print(i);l(int(i))
```

**Older python 3.8 only code**

```
i=input()
while i:print(i:=int(i))
```

[Try me!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFHI1PTikshM00h06qgKDOvBMi3BgqCGZr//wMA)

**Explination:**

<s>While this ties the best python 3 answer</s> thanks xnor for saving me a byte

This uses a few interesting properties to achieve what it does:

1. The input received is always a string when from a user input, thus the while-loop will start regardless if its a 1 or 0
2. <s>Inside the loop, we print the number for the first time, and simultaneously using the walrus operator which was introduced in python 3.8, we assign the integer value to i.</s> Using recursion, this code can now work in all versions of python 3, while it isn't a major improvement in bytes count, I'd still count making the code work in more versions an improvement!
3. Now, the value, if zero, is now converted from "0" to 0, meaning the loop will exit, otherwise if its 1, it keeps going!

I have tried hard to get lambdas to work, but every attempt ended up with more lines due to having to use recursion, if anyone has any ideas I am all ears! Meanwhile I will try to keep pushing this, the new version feels like it has more that can be pushed

Comment: Cute trick with the `int`. You can write `while i:` without parens saving a byte.

Comment: Dang, Thanks, One less byte means we are no longer tying haha

Answer (score 4):

## [Hello Hell](https://github.com/AMiller42/Hello-Hell), 34 bytes

```
[+^-/>]!*/*/>[+^>][+-/<]-/<[{*+}/]
```

[Try it Online!](https://hellohell.pythonanywhere.com?code=%5B%2B%5E-%2F%3E%5D!*%2F*%2F%3E%5B%2B%5E%3E%5D%5B%2B-%2F%3C%5D-%2F%3C%5B%7B*%2B%7D%2F%5D&inputs=0)

The first program in my new language - Hello Hell! For information on the commands, memory model, etc. check out the [repo](https://github.com/AMiller42/Hello-Hell).

Explanation:

```
[+^-/>]                             # Set the first 6 cells to 0
       !                            # Input
        */*/                        # Set the cell to 0 or 49 depending on input
            >[+^>]                  # Move to the 13th cell
                  [+-/<]-/<         # Set cells 8-13 to 0
                           [{*+} ]  # If 1, loop forever,
                                /   #  otherwise print 0
```

Comment: okay good I just wanted the upvoting to happen not the explaining thank you very cool

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 45 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations)

```
o→\left\{i=0:[0],join(1,o!)\right\}
i=0
o=0
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rtb6d9bjss?nographpaper) (Click the play button on the ticker up top (metronome icon) to run the program)

Desmos doesn't exactly have standard I/O support, but this should get the point across. Input is the i variable, output is the o variable. Each line is a separate expression, and the first expression needs to be in the ticker, as shown in the TIO.

Addendum: at the very least, this output method [is accepted by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25520/107310). Not sure about the input.

EDIT: a surprising -1, apparently `→` parses properly as an action! Unfortunately, it still costs 3 bytes, which is the same as `\to`, BUT it allows me to change `\to join` to `→join` since the parser gets confused by `\tojoin`

EDIT: -5 thanks to zygan on discord who showed me that an action *itself* can be piecewise, and also me realizing that `o!` is shorter than `o^o` and doesn't even have to rely on wacky edge case behavior lol

Comment: [44 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4znlc25ryb?nographpaper)

Comment: Actually, even better: [39 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nthcwav6z2?nographpaper)

Comment: @AidenChow wow! but i think +2, since it needs to be `o=[0]` in the initial state, with `o=0` it wont let you run the ticker because it expects a list. still, i had no idea you could do `lengthi`

Comment: Oh oops, didn't notice that. In that case, change `o.length` to `length(o)` for 40 bytes.

Comment: [33 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkqntvgrmg?nographpaper). I think this is about as low as it can get, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @AidenChow you should post that, its significantly shorter than mine and uses a somewhat different approach methinks

Comment: Will do, I have posted my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Pure [CPython 3.10 bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dis.html), 6 bytes

"Pure" means no constants and no names are allowed. As a result, the only method of input is by starting with values on the stack.

...and Python bytecode's only way to jump backwards (and therefore the only way to loop) uses "absolute" addressing, so my code assumes it is placed starting at instruction offset 3 (byte offset 6).

Hex of code: `04 00 46 00 70 03`

Disassembly of code:

```
    >>    6 DUP_TOP
          8 PRINT_EXPR
         10 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP      3 (to 6)
```

Takes an integer on the stack. The easiest way to put `0` or `1` on the stack is:

```
          0 LOAD_ASSERTION_ERROR
          2 BUILD_TUPLE              X
          4 GET_LEN
```

Change `X` to `0` or `1`. In hex, this is `4a 00 66 00 1e 00` (for `1`) or `4a 00 66 01 1e 00` (for `0`).

This will crash the interpreter for an input of `0` due to a buffer overflow. If this is not acceptable, add 2 bytes (append `53 00` (`RETURN_VALUE`)).

[Attempt This Online! (0)](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU3_zNyC_KIShaTMvMTi5MxMneLKYp2SyoLUYq7UitRkDTBTzzk_JTUEyNIw0IFASyCGadFLNEqKz0it0EhSUlJaWlqSpmtxU9MkUcHAQMHMDEQapgJJLgMTENsELGJuoGBgrGBqDGRDNXgC9eoVpRbkJCanAg2KyVPSARqniSSkABHR1NGAISUlEDIACUNENHWqazUhBi5YAKEB)

[Attempt This Online! (1)](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU3_zNyC_KIShaTMvMTi5MxMneLKYp2SyoLUYq7UitRkDTBTzzk_JTUEyNIw0IFASyCGadFLNEqKz0it0EhSUlJaWlqSpmtxU9MkUcHAQMHMTMHAUMEwFcjmMjABiZiYgUhzAwUDYwVTYyAbqsETqFevKLUgJzE5FWhQTJ6SDtA4TSQhBYiIpo4GDCkpgZABSBgioqlTXasJMXDBAggNAA)

---

I'm going to use this opportunity to explain how CPython bytecode works. It's just an array of bytes, which are in `opcode, oparg` pairs.

For example, (hex) `01 02 03 04` is `instruction_01(arg=02); instruction_03(arg=04)`.

[The list of instructions is given in the documentation for the standard library `dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions), although you sometimes need to dig about in Python's [`ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Python/ceval.c) to see exactly how they work.

In Python, bytecode is contained in a code object, which carries some metadata like source file lines, but the most important things are an array of constants (`co_consts`) and an array of names (`co_names`). In order to load a literal value, it must be loaded from `co_consts`; in order to lookup a global variable, its name must be in `co_names`. When I said I'm using "pure" bytecode, I mean that these arrays are both empty - so I can't use any literals (integers, strings, tuples, etc.), and I can't use any global variables, builtins, imports, or even look up any attributes. This allows an extremely minimal wrapper script (see the ATO link).

This leaves me with only [`PRINT_EXPR`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dis.html#opcode-PRINT_EXPR) for output (or leaving a value on the stack), and no input at all other than taking a value already on the stack.

The truth machine is actually the easy part of this code, to be honest: it's essentially `do { print x } while (x)`.

Loading an integer is a bit more involved: first I use `LOAD_ASSERTION_ERROR` to put a value on the stack. What value it is doesn't particularly matter, but this is one of only a few instructions I'm aware of that can load an object without any `consts`.

Then I use `BUILD_TUPLE(1)` to make the tuple `(AssertionError,)`, and take its length with `GET_LEN` which is `1`. To load `0` is a bit simpler: you only need

```
          0 BUILD_TUPLE              0
          2 GET_LEN
```

Although you can perfectly well leave the `LOAD_ASSERTION_ERROR` before that, to conveniently switch between loading `0` and `1`.

---

### Sidenote

`GET_LEN` is new in Python 3.10, so a historic method would have had to involve boolean <-> integer conversion, which is a bit more interesting IMO:

```
          0 LOAD_ASSERTION_ERROR
          2 DUP_TOP
          4 IS_OP                    0
          6 DUP_TOP
          8 BINARY_MULTIPLY
         10 PRINT_EXPR
```

This performs `AssertionError is AssertionError`, which is `True`. Then it does `True * True` to get the integer `1`.

`IS_OP(0)` can be replaced with `IS_OP(1)` to do `AssertionError is not AssertionError`, which gives `False`, which gives `0`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 13 bytes

```
?!<(@^\<.#^)/
```

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=0#%3F!%3C(%40%5E%5C%3C.%23%5E)%2F)!

Unfolds to this:

```
    ?
   ! <
  ( @ ^
 \ < . #
^ ) / . .
```

[image]

As in every Trilangle program, control flow starts at the north corner heading southwest. `\|/_` reflect control flow, while `<^7>vL` change the direction conditionally (depending on both the stored value and the direction of the IP).

The IP starts on the red path, where it encounters the following instructions:

- `?`: Read an integer from STDIN
- `!`: Write an integer to STDOUT (with trailing newline)
- `(`: Decrement
- `\`: Redirect control flow
- `<`: Branch

Upon reaching the branch instruction, the number inputted will already have been outputted once, and the stored value will be one less than that: `-1` if the input is 0, or `0` if the input is 1. The branch instruction proceeds left for negative values and right otherwise.

If the value inputted was 0, the program follows the green path, which immediately hits `@` (end program). Otherwise, it follows the blue path:

- `/`: Redirect control flow
- `)`: Increment, to cancel out the decrement instruction from earlier
- `^`: Redirect control flow

  (Walk off the edge of the board, and wrap around to the southeast corner)
- `.`: No-op
- `#`: Skip the next instruction

After encountering `#`, the IP jumps into the middle of the yellow loop. `!` prints out the stored value (1) repeatedly, and the other two characters keep it in the loop.

`<^` is not the only combination of control flow manipulators that works. I've found that at least the following pairs also work: `<7`, `<v`, `<<`, `L>`, `^>`, `>>`. Interestingly, `<\` causes it to print every odd number twice (1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, ...). All other pairs I've tried exhibit one of three behaviors:

- Loop without hitting `!` (e.g. `L<`)
- Exit early, printing out finitely many numbers (e.g. `<_`)
- Print a couple 1's before going back to the start and waiting for more input (e.g. `<|`)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 8 bytes

```
q~{_o}h;
```

There's no point in linking to the online interpreter, because that one doesn't like infinite loops.

This one works as well, printing newlines:

```
q~{_p}h;
```

#### Explanation

```
q~   e# Read and evaluate input.
{    e# While the top of the stack is truthy (i.e. 1.).
  _o e# Print a copy of the value on the stack.
}h
;    e# We only get here if the value was 0. If so, discard the other 0 on the stack.
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```
main=interact x
x"1"=cycle"1"
x a=a
```

The input must not be terminated by a newline. This works for me: `echo -n 1 | ./truth-machine`.

Edit: thanks @Zgarb for 3 bytes.

Comment: One-liner (also 35 byte): [`main=interact(\x->[1,read x..1]>>x)`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM882M68ktSgxuUQjpkLXLtpQpyg1MUWhQk/PMNbOrkLz/38DAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: `main=interact(\[c]->[c,'1'..c])` is 31 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

Two years later, two bytes golfed off.

```
disp(input('')),while ans disp(1),end
```

This was a bit shorter than the original one, since it avoid having anything after `end`, thus saving a comma or semicolon, and it saves one more byte by avoiding the separate call to `disp(0)`.

Comment: Not sure if it worked for older versions of MATLAB but it surely doesn't work for R2019b. Because `input('')` is used as function parameter it's never saved to `ans` variable. It works fine for the Octave tho. And for that it can be even shorter: `disp(input('')),while 1 disp(1)end` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

## AppleScript, 93 Bytes

...this verbosity astounds me.

```
set a to(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned
repeat while a="1"
log 1
end
log 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 8 bytes

There are two programs that achieve 8 bytes:

```
Repeat not(Ans
Disp Ans
End
```

`Repeat` is TI-BASIC's do-until loop, so it doesn't check the condition the first time. The other way is recursion (name the program `prgmT`):

```
Disp Ans
If Ans
prgmT
```

Both take input from `Ans`; call using `0:prgmT` or `1:prgmT`.

Comment: TIL the TI-84 doesn't have tail-call optimization for recursive programs. :(

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 7 bytes

```
nd$,N?.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nd%24%2CN%3F%2E&input=1) (DON'T click <kbd>Run</kbd>!)

#### Explanation

```
n     Take integer from input
d     Duplicate
$,    0 if 0, 1 otherwise
N     Output as integer
?.    Halt if 0, continue otherwise
```

This works because `n` pushes -1 if the input is empty...which is truthy! Also, Minkolang is toroidal so when the program counter moves off the right edge, it wraps around to the left edge and continues.

Answer (score 3):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), <s>21</s> 16 [bytes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

TeaScript is JavaScript for golfing, created by user [Vɪʜᴀɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40695/v%c9%aa%ca%9c%e1%b4%80%c9%b4).

```
for(;alert×|x;);
```

The input is automatically stored in variable `x`. `×` (U+00D7 Multiplication Sign) is a shortcut for `(x)`.

Try it in the [online interpreter](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)

Comment: See [this line](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript/blob/master/teascript.js#L198) for an explanation of the bug behavior.

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ Ah, yes. That explains why `whil(x)` did the same thing, but not `whi(x)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/about.html), <s>355</s> 321 bytes

<s>As with the other answers I've written in Jasmin, there isn't a whole lot of golf going on here. This code is (almost) exactly the code obtained from running `javap` on the class file generated by [intrepidcoder's java submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62792/31441). The one neat golfing trick I found was avoiding the usual `.limit locals` line by reusing local variable 0.</s>

## Some code golf four years later

1. Shorten the invocation of `print` by extending `PrintStream`
2. `ldc 2` is shorter than `iconst_2`
3. Manipulating the stack with `dup` and `swap` is shorter than using locals variables with `iload_0` and `istore_0`.

After these changes, the compiled class file needs to be executed with `java -noverify`.

---

```
.class L
.super java/io/PrintStream
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 4
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
getstatic java/lang/System/in Ljava/io/InputStream;
invokevirtual java/io/InputStream/read()I
ldc 2
irem
dup2
invokevirtual L/print(I)V
dup
ifgt $-5
return
.end method
```

Comment: Would it be any shorter to put the code in an initializer block and not have a `main` method?

Comment: @feersum I've never been able to get static blocks to work using `java version "1.8.0_60"`. I think static block are only accepted by  java in version 1.6 and earlier.  I don't have the correct version to test it so, I'll leave my answer as is for now.

Comment: +1 for golfing this 4 years later

Answer (score 3):

## , 6 chars / 11 bytes

```
↻ôï|ï;
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=1&code=%E2%86%BB%C3%B4%C3%AF%7C%C3%AF%3B)</kbd>

Comment: Is the language name supposed to be "ESMin", or just five boxes?

Comment: ESMin in double-struck. It doesn't show up properly in some fonts, though... :(

Comment: Ah, okay. I can only see the [double-struck letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold) ℂ, ℍ, ℕ, ℙ, ℚ, ℝ, and ℤ.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 29 27 bytes

2 bytes brilliantly saved by @Giuseppe

```r
x=scan();while({cat(x);x})1
```

Comment: the other R solution isn't valid, but there's another two bytes you can squeeze out of this! [click here to spoil it](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVozo5sUSjQtO6olbT8P9/AA)

Comment: @Giuseppe that is great.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
For[Print[i=Input[]],i>0,Print@i]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), 16 bytes

```
?0=[0!$](1^1!)$
```

Ungolfed:

```
? 0 = [           ~ Read a number from STDIN and test it for equality with 0
  0 ! $           ~ If equal, print 0 and exit
]
( 1 ^             ~ While true,
  1 !             ~ Print 1
)$                ~ End of program
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PoGo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/PoGo), 10 bytes

```
ifpouftogo
```

### Explanation:

- if - accept numerical input and place the result into the current memory cell
- po - add current position in code to the top of the po stack
- uf - output the value in the current memory cell as a number
- to - execute the following command only if the value in the current memory cell is >0
- go - pop the most recent po location off the stack and jump there

The "po" stack is a call stack used for flow control.

#### The program in pseudo code:

```
read int x
do:
    print x
while x > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 6 bytes

```
?|:!:/
```

In the case of a `0` input, this [terminates with an error](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/8478). For a beautiful solution which exits cleanly, [see Sp3000's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62766/8478).

Since the code is linear, the instruction pointer will move back and forth on the code (it will turn around when hitting a dead end, executing the instruction at the end only once). So what is happening?

```
?  Read the input as an integer.
|  Compute the bitwise OR of the top two stack elements (there is an infinite supply of
   zeroes at the bottom). This is a no-op at this point.
:  Duplicate the input.
!  Print it as an integer.
:  Duplicate the input.
/  Divide the input by itself. If the input was 0, the interpreter will throw an error,
   polluting STDERR, but we can ignore that. STDOUT remains unchanged. If the input was
   1, then 1/1 just yields 1 again and execution continues leftwards.
:  Duplicate the 1.
!  Print it.
:  Duplicate the 1.
|  Bitwise OR between 1 and 1 gives 1.
?  Try reading another integer. But we're at EOF, so this pushes 0.
   We're in a dead end, so the IP turns around and moves back to the right.
|  Bitwise OR between 1 and 0 gives 1.
   At this point, the state is exactly the same, as the first time we hit |, so from here
   on it's an infinite loop, printing two 1s per iteration.
```

Answer (score 3):

### COMMAND.COM, 12 + 10 + 11 = 33 bytes

`0.BAT`:

```
@ECHO 0
@EXIT
```

`1.BAT`:

```
@ECHO 1
@1
```

Start `COMMAND.COM` with the above two files in the current directory. Then when it requests input, type either 0 or 1. Also works with `CMD.EXE`.

If you don't want the Microsoft version and copyright then you can use `CMD /K ECHO OFF` instead. I've therefore added 11 bytes for this, but subtracted 4 bytes, as you no longer need the `@`s at the start of each line.

If command-line arguments are acceptable and you are allowed use `COMMAND /C 0` or `COMMAND /C 1` then you can remove the `@EXIT` from `0.BAT`. In that case the size is 7 + 11 + 1 + 1 = 20 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
0io=v
  ^1?|
```

Still working on a oneliner (if it's possible).

Answer (score 3):

## Squirrel, 48 bytes

```
local a=stdin.readn('b')-48;do print(a) while(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Quipu](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Quipu), 20 bytes

```
\/1&
/\/\
1&??
>>
::
```

Answer (score 3):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
j{.o}w
```

When *0* is inputted, *0* is outputted and the program ends. When *1* is inputted, *1* is outputted forever.

Explanation:

```
j     Get input as Number
{  }w While the input is 1
 .o    Print the 1
      Print the stack when code ends, which will only contain 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## Binary-Encoded Golfical, 11+1 (`-x` flag)= 12 bytes

Hexdump of binary encoding:

```
00 40 02 15 14 1B 1A 17 14 24 1D
```

Original image:

[image]

Magnified 125x, with color  labels:

[image]

Rough translation:

```
*p=readnum
lbl A
print *p
if *p!=0 goto A
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf

### 0 Bytes

I found out what to do with the zero-byte program! I made a truth machine.

[0 as input](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#input=MA)

[1 as input](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#input=MQ)

Comment: Congrats, you have made the most boring answer on this challenge! ಠ_ಠ +1

Comment: @zyabin101 *bows* thank you.

Comment: This appears to be invalid as the second 1 seems to be a 3.

Comment: @Makonede It worked 5 years ago. Quite frankly I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Based on the JS code I figure it's just a bug. Still though, quite strange

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I kind of love that an app with literally no code used to work but now doesn't. Not really sure what you can do with that!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
Di[D?
```

Explanation:

```
D      # Duplicate input
 i     # If True (or 1), do
  [    # Infinite loop
   D   # Duplicate top of the stack
    ?  # Pop a, print a with no newline
```

Comment: Based on the date this was posted I assume implicit input wasn't a thing yet back then, but both `D` can be removed now to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 35 bytes

```
@IF %1==0 (exit)
:l
@echo 1&goto l
```

Please, anyone who can golf this more is more than welcome to.

Comment: -2 bytes by removing the parentheses from the if statement

Answer (score 3):

## [Whenever](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/whenever.html), 72 bytes

From the webpage:

> ## Introduction
>
> Whenever is a programming language which has no sense of urgency. It does things whenever it feels like it, not in any sequence specified by the programmer.
>
> ## Design Principles
>
> - Program code lines will always be executed, eventually (unless we decide we don't want them to be), but the order in which they are executed need not bear any resemblance to the order in which they are specified.
> - Variables? We don't even have flow control, we don't need no steenking variables!
> - Data structures? You have got to be kidding.

The official java interpreter doesn't seem to handle read() but the spec says it should work so.

```
1 -2,2#read();
2 defer(1) again(2) print("1");
3 defer(1||2) print("0");
```

The program works like this:

- Initially 1, 2 and 3 are on the list but 2 and 3 must wait until 1 is gone.
- When 1 is executed it removes 2 and then adds 2 back stdin times.  Therefore:

  - 2 is only on the list if stdin was 1.
  - 3 must wait until 2 is gone so it can only execute if stdin was 0.
- If 2 is executed it will add itself to the list again and print '1'.
- If 3 is executed (meaning 2 is not on the list) it will print '0'.
- At this point we will be in one of two states:

  - 2 will be on the list printing '1' and 3 will be perpetually waiting
  - 1, 2 and 3 will all be gone and the program will end.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>16</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
x=scan();while(x)cat(1);0
```

Edited to read x

Comment: this isn't valid, because the `0` will be printed out with an additional `[1] ` preceding it, and the post states that _the output must only be either a 0 followed by either one or no newline or space, or infinite 1s with each 1 followed by either one or no newline or space._

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch, 12 bytes

[image: Script]
I love how Scratch can be so self-explanatory in the right contexts.

Comment: Your list name counts as bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaot++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Gaot%2B%2B), 125 bytes

```
bleeeeeeeeeeet
bleeeet bleeeeeet
bleeeeeeeeeeeeet
bleeeeeeeeeeeeet
bleeeeeeeeeeeeet
bleeeeeeeeeeeeet
bleeeeeeeeet
bleeeeeeeet
```

Compressed: `11e4e6e13e13e13e13e9e8e6e`

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/kc_kennylau/nbda5va6/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Churro](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Churro), <s>100</s> 95 bytes

```
{========={o}{*}======}{*}======}{={*}{={o}{={o}{={*}{={o}{======={*}{==={*}{======={*}{===={*}
```

**Explanation**

Churro is a stack-based esolang where the only syntax element is, well, [churros](http://google.com/images?q=churro)! Or rather, ASCII-art representations of churros. An example of such a churro is `{o}====}`.

In Churro, each churro has three characteristics:

1. Its orientation; whether it's facing left (`{o}====}`) or right (`{===={o}`).
2. Its filling; whether it's filled (`{*}==}`) or not (`{o}==}`).
3. Its tail length; the number of `=`s in the churro is the length of its tail.

Left-facing churros are integer literals; their tail length is their value, while their filling status is their sign. Filled churros are negative, while unfilled churros are positive.

Right-facing churros are operators; their tail length is which operator they represent, according to this table:

```
{{o}           pop A; discard A
{={o}          pop A, B; push B + A
{=={o}         pop A, B; push B - A
{==={o}        pop A; if A == 0, jump to churro after matching occurrence of {==={o}
{===={o}       pop A; if A != 0, jump to churro after matching occurrence of {==={o}
{====={o}      pop A, B; store B in memory location A
{======{o}     pop A; push the value in memory location A to stack
{======={o}    pop A; print A as an integer
{========{o}   pop A; print A as an ASCII character
{========={o}  read a single character from STDIN and push it to the stack
{=========={o} exit the program
```

Filled operator churros have the same behaviour, but peek at the stack instead of popping from it.

With that, here's the ungolfed, explained version of the Churro truth-machine:

```
{========={o}    read char from stdin
{*}======}       push -6
{*}======}       push -6
{={*}            push -6 + -6 = -12
{={o}            pop -6, -12; push -6 + -12 = -18
{={o}            pop -6, -18; push -6 + -18 = -24
{={*}            push input + -24
{={o}            pop -24, input + -24; push input + -48 (convert char to int)
{======={*}      print input as integer
{==={*}          if input == 0 jump to matching churro
{======={*}      print input as integer
{===={*}         if input != 0 jump back to matching churro
```

I'm using [TheLastBanana's Haskell interpreter](https://github.com/TheLastBanana/Churro) to interpret this. Installation instructions can be found there.

Finally, here's the "pure" version (no comments, line length 80, spaces between churros), as output by `purify truth.ch`:

```
{========={o} {*}======} {*}======} {={*} {={o} {={o} {={*} {={o} {======={*} 
{==={*} {======={*} {===={*}
```

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to Martin Ender!*

Comment: And now I want a dulce de leche and some doughnuts...

Answer (score 3):

### dc, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```dc
?[pd1=@]ds@x
```

**Run:**

```sh
dc -f truth_machine.dc <<< "1"
```

Adding to the diversity of languages used, I present a dc solution that works as follows:

```dc
?              # reads the input and pushes it on top of the stack
[pd1=@]ds@x    # stores the macro command [pd1=@] into register '@' and executes it
   p           # prints the value on top of the stack
   d           # makes a duplicate that is pushed on top
   1=@         # pushes 1, pops two numbers and if they are equal, the macro from
               #register '@' is executed (again), thus making an infinite cycle
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Moorhen 1](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Moorhen) (or original creators version 1 [here](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/releases/tag/v1.0)), 38 bytes

The original language creator has decided to add new instructions, which would change the existing ones. Hence, this language is in Moorhen version one

```
op pa id el pa id el ai op id ai pi ai
```

Note this doesn't print if input is 1, because printing only happens at halting, so it just puts infinite ones on stack

### Explanation:

Commands can be (most of) all english words, and the command they execute depends on md5 hash mod 7. I used some length two words that corresponded to each of the seven commands

`re`: push 0

`op`: increment ToS

`pa`: decrement ToS

`el`: rotate stack (place ToS on BoS)

`pi`: dupe ToS

`id`: peek TOS, skip if it is non-zero

`ai`: flip pointer direction

there are two main segments of code

```
op pa id el pa id el
```

```
ai op id ai pi ai
```

---

```
op pa id el pa id el
```

This code, when run forwards, will have the pointer leave to the right side, with the initial value on the stack, minus one (`0 -> -1`, `1 -> 0`). When run backwards, with `[-1]` as stack, it leaves the to the left side with [0] as the stack. When it leaves to the left, it will print the stack, items joined with spaces, so it will print 0. It uses "nops", commands that don't do anything under certain circumstances, or are a pair of inverses.

(the reason the comments look funny is because the interpreter ignores non-words, including real words that are hyphenated)

```
op pa                nop-when-running-forwards
      id el          nop-with-only-one-value-on-stack-and-running-forward
            pa       decrement-
               id el nop-with-only-one-value-on-stack-and-running-forward
                     [go to next part of code]
```

with all these nops forward, its essentially `pa` when running forward. However, backwards, with -1 on stack:

```
el                   nop-with-only-one-value-on-stack
   id pa             skip-pa,when-TOS-nonzero(-1,is-non-zero)
         el          nop-with-only-one-value-on-stack
            id pa    skip-pa,when-TOS-nonzero(-1,is-non-zero)
                  op increment-
                 [end,print-stack(with,-1,coming-in,print-0)]
```

With -1, backwards, it's essentially `op` (then implicit print)

---

The code that is at the right of that code:

```
ai op id ai pi ai
```

given -1, it will just reflect it back. Given 0, it will increment it, then enter a loop of duping ToS, which will be 1.

```
ai            reflect-pointer-direction-if-TOS-non-zero
   op         increment-
      id      skip-next-command-if-non-zero. This-command-skips-into-the-middle-of-a-loop:

        ai pi ai    this-is-the-loop. pointer-starts-on-pi,because-it-skipped-the-first-ai

           Here is a visualisation of how it executes
           pi       dupe-TOS (1)
              ai    reverse-if-ToS-is-nonzero (it is)
           pi       dupe-TOS (1) -again
        ai          reverse-if-ToS-is-nonzero (it is)
           pi       dupe-TOS (1) -again
           ...      this keeps happening
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 41 bytes

```
input n
print n
while"1"=n
print n
repeat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0otyKgs@v8/M6@gtEQhj6ugKDMPRJdnZOakKhkq2SKEilILUhNL/v83BAA)

A main design goal of Zephyr was that code should be readable and understandable. Looks like this holds true even when the code is maximally golfed. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 617 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.1 is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:s 1 r 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.Go to Crime Lab:n 1 r 2 r 2 l.Switch to plan "z" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 4 l 2 l.[r]Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:s 1 l 2 r 1 l.Go to Zoom Zoom:s 1 r 1 l 2 r.Go to Cyclone:w.Switch to plan "r".[z]0 is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 4 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#nVHLCsIwEPyVoRdvQcVTrwpeBAUPgsVDLGldrNmSRIr9@do01ieIeNiEfc7sbDNnOMaKrcMyyyhVcYURitaM/8WK0uO5hEQprVU6VwY5k85919TQSWEh92IEsqgkOZ@RDhtDTpmBxUyV7EQAeQ3GtsfA@GecMOjux7qbMe6sEOuKXHrwFWUhNaI6AmXQDNbqieB3rEtatOU9UvBanMmNZ2J2v7R/q3kSW3zKb2@SBPlDfst86p4X0cwbyepDABOJpN4N/zjOY@H/N3kcx2/SNFc)

There are shorter programs but they kept running out of gas. Here's the ungolfed version:

```
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
1 is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: south 1st right 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
Go to Crime Lab: north 1st right 2nd right 2nd left.
Switch to plan "z" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 4th left 2nd left.
[r]
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: south 1st left 2nd right 1st left.
Go to Zoom Zoom: south 1st right 1st left 2nd right.
Go to Cyclone: west.
Switch to plan "r".
[z]
0 is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 4th left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Duck Duck Goose](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duck_Duck_Goose), 911 bytes

```
duck duck duck goose

duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck duck

duck duck duck

duck duck duck duck goose

duck duck duck

duck duck

duck duck duck goose

duck



duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck duck

duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck duck duck

duck duck

duck duck duck goose

duck

duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose



duck

duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck

duck duck duck

duck duck goose

duck duck duck

duck

duck duck goose

duck

duck goose



duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck duck goose

duck

duck duck

duck duck goose

duck duck duck

duck goose
```

Includes 2 trailing newlines. I can't remove the newlines, they are instructions.

Answer (score 3):

### [Thotpatrol](http://esolangs.org/wiki/thotpatrol), <s>311</s> 219 bytes

Credit to @MickyT for shaving 92 bytes off

```
JACKING IN
DM THAUGHTY JO
  JO
  JO
❤PRIME ASSETS❤ JO INTERROGATE ©1©
  JO
INTERCEPT MALIGNANT COMMUNICATIONS
REPORT UNPATRIOTIC ACTIVITY
```

This is a fairly uninteresting truth machine the core structure is as follows:

```
input a
print a
while a == 1
    print a
end while
```

Here is a link to an implementation in Java:
https://github.com/MindyGalveston/thotpatrol-

Comment: what in the world is this language?

Comment: This language is a pet project of mine. Its core eccentricity is that there is a finite and non-accessible list of allowed variable names. The only way to programatically allocate data is by abusing string variables and using them as databases or trial and error automatic variable naming which does not have a hard upper complexity limit. Have fun, and I'd love to answer any questions!

Comment: How is this 318 bytes? It's 243 UTF-8 bytes, or 172 characters.

Comment: I forgot to update the code when I updated the byte count and the logic, You're completely right I made a mistake. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Also is `Jo` or `Bo` acceptable variable names?

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/GTkWKgT8) is what I was trying to say before about a slightly different structure

Comment: works perfectly! I updated the answer with your changes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dreaderef](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/Dreaderef), 11 bytes

```
5*1 1 5?8-1
```

Takes input from the command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SylKTUxJLUpN@//fVMtQwVDB1N5C1/D///@GAA)

### Explanation

This program consists of eight numbers. These numbers are grouped into instructions; each instruction consists of a *label*, which is the first number, and zero or more *arguments*, which follow the label. Instructions with different labels can have different numbers of arguments, but the parsing of instructions happens at execution time (which allows self-modification). The numbers in the program are written to the tape from position 0 at the beginning of the program; each label and argument occupies its own cell, and the instruction pointer occupies the cell at location -1.

```
5 *
1 1  5
? 8 -1
```

Dreaderef's preprocessor allows you to write *aliases* that stand in for numbers representing instruction labels. Using aliases makes the program look like this:

```
0.   numo  *
2.   deref 1  5
5.   ?     8 -1
```

(The leading numbers are position labels and are treated as comments.) Before the program executes, `*` is replaced with the input integer.

```
0.   numo  *
```

The first instruction is `numo`, which outputs its argument (either 0 or 1) in decimal without a trailing newline.

```
2.   deref 1  5
```

`deref` reads the tape at the position indicated by its first argument. It then writes that value to the tape at the position indicated by its second argument. This means that here `deref` copies cell 1 (the input integer and argument to `numo`) to cell 5 (part of the next instruction).

```
5.   ?     8 -1
```

This instruction is interesting in that the *label* is dynamically generated by the previous instruction (`?` is an alias for 0 in Dreaderef, but it is intended to convey that a given cell is uninitialized and will not be read until it is written to). During execution, it will be set to either 1 or 0 depending on the input integer. Proceeding from here requires some knowledge about what labels map to what instructions:

- The instruction with label 0 is `end`, which terminates execution.
- The instruction with label 1 is `deref`.

If the input integer was 0, the `end` instruction causes the program to terminate, and the other two numbers are ignored.

If the input integer was 1, the instruction looks like this:

```
5.   deref 8 -1
```

Cell 8 is past the end of the program, meaning that its value defaults to 0. The 0 is copied into cell -1, which is Dreaderef's instruction pointer. This means that execution jumps back to position 0, which is the start of the program. Because `*` is read before execution of the program, the same input (1) is reused, and the program outputs and loops again.

Answer (score 3):

### Rockstar, 34 Bytes

Rockstar is a quite new computer programming language, designed for creating programs that are also song lyrics. Rockstar is heavily influenced by the lyrical conventions of 1980s hard rock and power ballads.

```
Listen to your heart
Say your heart
While your heart is not empty
Scream it
```

But yes, you are right, it's longer than 34 bytes, but so poetic, I couldn't resist get some lyrics in. You could even sing it!. Here's the golfed version:

```
Listen to X
Say X
While X
Say X
```

Comment: Which interpreter are you using? Wouldn't the input be treated as a string, which is truthy? Also, would the `Until X` loop until `X` is truthy, rather than while `X` is truthy?

Comment: @JoKing You are right, the golfed version was incorrect, I changed the `Until` loop to the `While` loop. (it did not change the code length).
To answer your question, I use my interpreter: https://github.com/gaborsch/rocky - that worked the expected way, too, so it was my mistake, not the interpreter's.

Comment: The input is numeric in this case, so `0` is coerced to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Malbolge](https://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge.shtml), 257 bytes

```
(aONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:98765FD21dd!-,O*)y'&v5#"!DC|Qzf,*vutsrqpF!Clk|ih
gfed9(T&6KoOHZYXWVUTSRQPONM]KJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876"'~g|edybav_zyxwvotsrq
pSnPlOjibKfedcba`_XA??ZYRW:UTSLQ3ONMLK.IHGFE>CBA@?"=<;:38765432s0/.n,+*)
j!&%f{"!~}|_zyxZvYnsrqpRnmlkjML:f_^GF!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7bUoJAAADQd/5iaURFMpO0pJIMQgsMQUthpgjkkriCpW5h5K8Ty3M/cOasbOjEMPCyrGKrj0NFfrgf9KU7Ubjt3fDd66tLrnNx3m5JYvPUdcExo9LVpEyh1hEJRCHV9j5Do9128/mxloAAl@ninQh8z@1UJlRbjtWBacymz0@Tsa6Ncv7lf54sH4LUcxPHRtY@@f5CMRaJ9TgaQTVcOHIuzh37zZr1eN409CmXi4rGFuF6IXYLkcQii8NnbHPTOKlHTI2uEiGgSv4PCQ6/KfZNZER4rEcruAyHCudbr30JZFnjDw)

From [esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Malbolge)

Quite the abomination, isn't it?

In fact, this language is so horrible, I don't think anyone "programmed" this in the traditional sense. If I'm remembering correctly, this was found by a search program that basically brute-forced for possible Malbolge programs that worked as a truth machine.

Comment: The program was made by esolang's Malbolge expert [Malbranche](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Malbranche), who is amazing and certainly can program it in other ways than brute force. You may be thinking of the first Malbolge "Hello, world!", which was indeed found by search.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you for the correction, it does make sense that a Hello World program would be much longer and more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust compiler (nightly)](https://rust-lang.org), 86 bytes

```rust
#![feature(log_syntax)]macro_rules!t{(0)=>{log_syntax!{0}};(1)=>{log_syntax!{1}t!{1}}}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f264178e8b81a71a6da92302d590860)

Readable version:

```rust
#![feature(log_syntax)]

macro_rules! truth_machine {
    (0) => {
        log_syntax!(0);
    };
    (1) => {
        log_syntax!(1);
        truth_machine!(1);
    };
}

truth_machine!(0);
truth_machine!(1);
```

### Explanation

As the only way to iterate over anything other than the inputs of a macro is recursion, an infinite loop will always end in a stack overflow. I'm considering this error message "constant output of your language's interpreter that cannot be suppressed," as there's no other way to "infinitely" loop. The time for this to occur is dependent on the stack size, and thus most real-world macros will attempt to perform multiple operations per iteration to avoid this. Since this takes more space, I didn't do this. The only ways for a macro to give output are:

- `compile_error!`, a builtin which will immediately terminate compilation with a message, and is thus not valid for this challenge
- `log_syntax!`, an unstable builtin which will print its input to the compiler's stdout, with a newline appended
- Returning a value from the macro directly, which directly conflicts with the concept of an infinite loop

I chose to use `log_syntax!`, as I decided it was the only option that would follow the rules of the challenge. However, it requires a nightly compiler, and 23 additional characters in the source to enable. The syntax of macros is pretty fixed, but one trick I found is that macros called with `macro!{}` instead of `macro!();` do not require a semicolon after, and are thus one character shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Acrostic](https://github.com/Mercerenies/acrostic-lang/), <s>89</s> 45 bytes

*-44 bytes by running the initial input command backwards to output the zero (thanks Jo King for the idea!).*

```
     R
DOUBLE
  N  A
PROVIDED
R
I
NIL
T
END
D
```

[Try it online...?](https://repl.it/repls/PlasticEmbarrassedProfiler) (This esolang has no official online interpreter; that link takes you to a repl.it link with [my own unofficial Python interpreter](https://github.com/WinslowJosiah/acrostic-py) loaded in, complete with the truth machine program. If I can find/make a more proper online interpreter, I'll link that instead.)

Acrostic is an esolang designed by [Mercerenies](https://github.com/Mercerenies) for which programs take the form of crosswords, which are traversed word-by-word during program execution.

First, END is run backwards, which starts the program. PRINTED is then run backwards, which will take a numerical input and push it onto the stack. If the top of the stack is 0, the PROVIDED branch is not taken, and instead NIL is run (which does nothing). Because there are no other words to run from there, PRINTED is executed forwards, and then END is executed, ending the program. If, however, the top of the stack is nonzero, the PROVIDED branch is taken, READ is run backwards (outputting the number), DOUBLE is executed backwards (pushing `-2`), UNO is executed forwards (pushing `1`), and PROVIDED is executed (because the top of the stack is nonzero), looping this section forever.

It took me much trial and error to get an Acrostic truth machine this short, though IMHO it is a very clean and compact example. If only this language were easier to golf...

Comment: Thanks for the idea about reusing the read to print the zero @JoKing, I have a 46-byte solution now that I'm playing around with.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>4,</s> 3 bytes

-1 thanks to @Aaron Miller (uses implicit input for the 1s)

```
[{₴
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%5B%7B%E2%82%B4&inputs=1&header=&footer=)

Comment: [3 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%5B%7B%E2%82%B4&inputs=0&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller fixed

Comment: [Alternate 3 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%7B%7C%E2%82%B4&inputs=0&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Plumber](https://github.com/Radvylf/plumber), <s><sup>28</sup></s> 20 bytes

```
[]
=]]][=[]
  ][=[][
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##7RvbbqM49L1f4c3DCDYJDeTSaLK0mod52JF2dqV9dL0aNpCUipCIQKfVTL69axtDuBhjp0lvWlQVYh/O/RwfX7h17pztPPI3cf9u@rhIwnnsr0OwCZLVv9p87Xo94ETLrQ5@nAF83TkRSEI/3gIbkF5jG/hzTzN7oG/qxnYT@LF2fh1dXYc/r6PzpW6snI3mBcC@BF5gRN4mcDD4OfwHXiMbnS97oAM6urFx3M@hq/3hxDfG3PMD/IoReOEyvgHnwNLBr8BikCsnnt9o58YPs2ftMAHw8yeASJ9R7lIeyRV4MVg595hLyi2m7CaYsObM5z3MiU4YotQwUNbIKOo9MGD4yJVJm@IpiTNfh3Mn1gzDCL3v4FMUOQ8aIdovIDMWfhBoHYB51xnWHYfXkCgZU4FoVm5PVrg1M4uGofTCm@TyF0CLHzbeekEMBWwbdLZx5IfLjl6CI1fkxUkUEjhmqk5Hr4rken@t/TD@FGsDXcd6u/OiracVFEIuL9h6lPJX7CZeZPjb38PYW3oR5bCRMMS9qI6pEXxQAN7tH5muyG3PoLFYR58d7BupLFShxibZ3lD7JCvcnluggITCFe1CPHwZ@S7py62aGp@ZdJbDrZN4k8QFs5FGJ/DvvKLR7nvgoWg1GkOZR8F7BB8KYlLyuJOwUO0jCl9ipeA/8As2dJgEAfH/JTQ5bRanbchpG3HaxqW2sj2ZceIo8cqswQ5EHRymCJL/Nn2GNn2mLYg@w/QZdZDhh/Mgcb2tlujgwwdMdnIishxSF4eQ0hIaX5gGUVP6A5NiKKeqKFnjwsExwFwwvWFXBhoJfx97wmCGb79Rh2AeiBu63aJHUWfxUd1lMUNlry1hT3rgNiVwywhgJDmN2zINmgtzr/URvK1EMnsft5OAgEQHqAfk7hVURNdM1XZB1VW9F37Awg/sW/UMtOcuTQopXb1OV9WdZEllonJI@oTtAXEiJg0WoKL5Ml4W28R0IqghH2p3Vn5K/7vrAklVByy9s1R1K8p2lvM4ntWU@3h49jq9xMM4t3uvJTxSm1RTA2YqRkGfcV/M6KfU6zC7Bq7NE3Ft5lybQq7Ng7i2FLgueQfhr1WGLpPBymWwhDJYB8kwfBYZhrkMQ6EMQwUZqkH65KjEyf6gwBTmfJnIXaZCwyWNsvVG07lAJgMyRUAWA7JEQEMGNGwG2g8wCBRGDgA7Ih/J498mKnG9hR96brEA43RYTR3Dekezw2UFsY8tiMegbgfNWrnkFyKcfNbtipCZ0sjMdmSWNDKrHdlQGtmwCdluP5NhQ2/JHdDbcIf@Ud2h3z@iO4iRKbqDGJmiO/CQ1dwBtSUEWQkI9K14cE95m0iNh2oSp8SrGV88xKXcXEiObGlepvVt8@AnAKnHoVzonUTxg1bFm8@oeLOlIG1VvKmk@PrcVt79eWsMoji8YPWQ@XxuBU8o0OHWbg/6emZCJ5dEKWia8sN7rWpLSxRiS0gssDW834iDrjeNJa2ZmSoNNrrqHTmhu15pOlbYwBiDq3wZ8GOGd9aIjrtiy6eVM25njF/lfH/MaDbktp1EDCjV7s9kBgGO8kw2w9Ztyn/1iWNGTPgKU5M8G0Mla7UQP9SWaoX3a7VlX92W/Ze0Zf80tnyj5lM03YuZ7QQmQ28lew7UTGYe2WR78uZLm8xWizJRIb4v40atc5@xNNZpjnUsW9VC@2gyTU8i00RdJlsqtMTzpFciCjqeeZRlOrIoEL7PMaoyI9unPv3Jua8ySz1g4DrJyPVWig2e@toGh9PUHa/DkJydm5FoMYdw0dD9HpcVYHEhDhXPN9ilww5tKXly5DWfjPl0F3qcu9KkNY1fnHodLWeNbsyOctYuhEuok8J5lexIH40RdrRR1xu3EbOhjIfgQgaBelE3eSklttt3qsBaBn1ptzlcesYu42IqNOWUa4npQZaAbyew3pni4VsMgSflEfWi5jU439NEfrenXUZcpYxklJKVONWXx20v8/RXFo4oZRs7ce1kcg@4PEWIziEXYRoPMvM3Ss4ExxnyfYN95dk3adE54Ze99WXHUsXUQszF4W1JIS7tidqVo6aF3dLiEjYCbfRHckLZ5WKv4cwrQJWtEDHtsZzcpTX5FutpLgEb6eS/lqR2xChwHrsCxIoDPjkRyvo5ud2MH@4KKeIoaUIqVciki0rN31xzVMrotulm89hHJq80EWjk9BAZ4nrEarLzWIVBpT7hrNNtmftKTWifxBL9TIRp5yr9pIQmWOyxfbOFO6nd0Ozao24R@Uy958mTmOJERnDcQmW6cpDDXqbH4At@0id@Mj7EP9ULP6HDMkaO67DH4PF/D1bxYMVCdAe@3/iBh92YDCsLP3Q1zQt64F5nH8ztmx5oE/36K/3kK//cjA1n6YRqdrY720R@GGtf/v7zq5F@q@cvHrT0k8tvjxCd2QghaOMHAOgdPn7r0WU3ffb4Hw)

I figured Plumber could use some love, so I thought I'd give it a try. It's a pretty fun language to work with! There's no online interpreter for it, so the TIO link is to Javascript, with the interpreter in the header, [compliments of @RedwolfPrograms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58078028#58078028).

This simply takes in input, prints it, and if it is non-zero, it keeps printing it forever.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 6 bytes

```
{(())}
```

While the top of the stack is non-zero, push 1. Input to the stack is implicit, and output would also be, but if the program doesn't halt, nothing is outputted. However, one is continually pushed onto the stack, and it's the closest Brain-Flak can get to infinite output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDQ1Oz9v9/QwA)

Answer (score 3):

## <s>[Perl](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, with the following restrictions</s> [ppencode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ppencode), 15 bytes.

- <s>Use only keywords with lowercase alphabets only</s>
- <s>Separate each of them with just a space</s>

```perl
print while sin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRKE8IzMnVaE4M@//fwOuf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

### How it works

- `sin(0)` is zero
- `sin(1)` is not zero
- `-p` is for implicit I/O for line by line

### Alternatives

`sin` can be replaced with one of following keywords:

```perl
abs int oct hex
```

Comment: can you do `print while-$_`?

Comment: @JoKing if I had changed the restriction.

Comment: Oh, i don't know how I missed that oops

Answer (score 3):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to Aaroneous Miller for saving 2 bytes*

```
q@#@8*1-[.
```

No newlines/spaces.

### Explanation

```
q     { Input a number a number, `n` }
@#    { Output `n` }
@8*1- { Push `8*n-1` to stack (7 for 1, -1 for 0) }
[     { Jump backwards by that many instructions }
      { Goes to right after input for 7, just before halt for -1 }
.     { Halt }
```

ErrLess is a stack-based language I made for fun over the last few months. You can read the docs [here](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/), and I also started a [tutorial](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/tutorial.md).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VvrdtvGEf7Pp9hIdQBIJEUqaZrSphvHt@rEtlxb7WlDsTwgsCRhgwC8u7RIOc7PPkAfsS/izuwFWFxIyY7VpDpHlLDYnfnmurMXZhuxSJOvvs3Yh33yiIpgQUMyY@mSLITI@ODoaB6JLmfdhTj6ma38ZJIdUcZiyvmE0Rk/EozSo6UfJUeRoMujaTSPEjFZJVGQhvQoU@TNkG62Ib4gX/XIaSDSKWXkuHfcb0XLLGWC@Gye@YxT88w33PwroiVttYLY55xESTZoEfgJ6YxMJlESicnE5TSeeaodf/CxG/rCJ0PiOK28/5yKOEpotTujYsUSa9Qhcu9yEUZJl1E/lIO80aDTH5eISUJtwqNLOuz0LYrRTDaSO6Q3uJq86xVQAHHecTRAIuPbJXmKt/hyMK5KwerksWMnponLPK@EP6pqIqFzYPHIj8EONUgocL@AerGIYkpYN@I88wPQT0Fm1zBQDbwCu3ScgeZ3xlb09hV8klQQNgIDFPyIn4R5WwiuJ@oYDptp2gqVFFBppq0kOVNWN02CbSoslNbB7UG7KBwCRbEo6JB0VHs@gq4DmgnyNz9e0YeMpayR2Ai8DPwcuMMnOEcLzRVnaebGbRIVngbcIh4lXPgJ6APexREX3rkhiepx3YjcHZKefIjAH9ENYs8jKSMuPqs3bifyyJ2heVuPjbiL7CMliQVTIaP09a8IbRSNG2FxsDmiapP1/xAVwgHLrS1ICs8s9oWQ3XMw6CsNgPKUMYq1ZEBwpP6dAQ4KfkFiSxFdugbKoWtYUK9kKKYABGm2sbk3ca4qdyQHUc/iW1J2rEiH6WTlmkQihZ246zq1GTQ2yL3W3FXMjGDsRjHcIMN1ieFsknMMaxzbZGMx9dtkijFUZ9S2Gze60c5QvjTytDk6gdNlm1woiPgforyMMsW/yBU0Rkq7aGgxLy0x84HbmQObS2vgZtygZqRdVZuaQJ9RkHsa04FxpwufhaCmdzkV5xIys/Oj0y5a3mHLe7vFxRbPblliy1Pd8l5@Tv3gdZ38Bjv@wx76Hlve2S0etrh2y1NsWebkpRPw11E2CdLlkkKazVg6b5NMsLaRig9xZjEOnwQAo4/WNa91ju7L98HCxzBDKiMgopSagLJkGg7kIxcsSnDGws5qJtWzE/Qr7AXDceIxo0zTLZUukEPhbI1sLV6HmpnlnGrIUFql5CMSLQzolz0p7/@@qX8H@9uu4gKMQ8Du3crRtjUaS@tah7bWkRx0GsryoU0gIQ2fpYnR/1b9TsAfg9eY4bDLuEHRWm6KGRkcGGgO5MMwd@auhqNJVCyjONTs078R67haDThhGM0XIEa9sapb5CuI3qoEZQvtsrYG3iYTLJwaI8GrDShwT2rvgjQB4Cta8xEFvetnGU4yCMgre5iLmit6euQLW7vF5FoVVpZllnKg0mpL@3oosWQ02IYG65EKjCqKIcZ7rmx4AvhX0KsFQn93GJgM91uJA4Pn@oHQ@a0FghFheyS8//hIaKtFzW82IIzQ/9cRIVYZMP3oGhOHUdcMXqvSZi1rTSWOFKVMSY5pWAs01KYsFb6Qg9Ls6tK7mWJ9QJqZohXAoj6AOC4I@lsoiCWu5/KlUpphAOQVfYTSMj@ZU7ffNuQsMFDPKQLw2S5RicaFyc2KRzbjqqdVae2NJR2vQUtz5k9dDrQtNZn2iZs3yZAxjm@WpIhVDcBlgBzh4RCt/5VylgH6igzGAS6X0XUwGUktQsm2SviAhFEAGu3cxQ66QF0lpbwjG/f3ycuze/d/IKfPH764d3Zy@uxly9hJDoAkMYB6cZ/cT5MArJ/Ab7EukIYA6Coo8vbplnaZy8rW97Xx1bKw8nJqXpYjq5QzRtDJH9vRyumg3GVKDonvVcVaS7HuyS5XShRvl@hK/69Djhsgl7rHpqvvbScT10S6LUV6STPKrmOmOni/ETyOH/n2TIUo9ErZtzKLwfGFxPE8zQr9VdiXun8nuz/AtBXYuHHBoJbaMkzVcK/VqAzRQHcu6T6GKMrHpNlOAxds8hcqnLHNhHSd0eOckdrzld2v5mmT1n8ayceS/BOazMWitH9W8QfcErE1VdstO9tkerOsPLLTb@D6xOJK0llFqBpn2zolOkzSeSHnjrJO8n2cQjdbrGtmnqKjlStL3F5Y3JrssJOnZrPLFm1JH6uN1pbYLgiPG8b/ToXohZ99chYthR@G7NRsRkM2fxIJCP6Yt8qsYVJ0ev3jr77@/Td/@PaP/jSA@URJslpOKePNwuCeK4xuk/43Tbo@d9TMABWQHwibilkX3t5eB5cYpbrulzNTE6uXSm1nL06ePW6VKlVuKtWGdbReN8DoLXxHyDhQdVKASuKjPu5SW8lZT@5AL9fxPbYRi6UvoqBVR3qoppUw/IX21Qjl7lzsL6ehj7ULxPz6cOPhzOg36amj9LSaCjTJjUHo7IAw0REyt@O9SnCVExyQztorhWMDzQNJ8@kqFlEWb25MrIMdYh2pSSp6G4WfXgDJ1a4/o2H0trrHmud07XDro6NN6aXO4T9SliIKHqWJzuV6RG@HnJrpdvFuKQ2n4SpOf7F4yzS8Urxbn1k64LlduvNzYz3o9jmsdw0J7V4fKWr7Ora0BTaZ6X66zHwW8TRpyExDqYOHb1Z@HIkbC6JO/8BdD4cbb7s17ujKgnMiFn5yo0ju7AJyV9dtFFIVu3ksdy0sxmLfR@Ii4pQckSfpHMrfmJzK6h2cgjfY8GeVXE/PrpVZf746s36ppqtnD24sqX65I6n@JLmfvrgx5j/tYP5PyfzvN8j9n5uavU/FgrIGwwoVE5EQMSVnN4UIC7r1Qb93cLArLM4klu@jObmemyFVpLn2rnS3zBbz@c2Kebxbyue5lM@vLeVxk5BF8k0ES2PyKE4vGizclfz@7MeiWlvqc7NS70vZ@5E5X3ucirRUXW8veuVJ3ag3bqpga2w2Sgl6z3Q7n6bd@Y9i9E4yOrtIOxf@hsy3sKmfu1yX/kgVvkAkV1o@7tVy2wo8wy2G8ja8bfVXgGGYiQHJupMJpwKvZk0mLszPLm4Bdl5ZG7jgFq/MhmAhVSauK8C4ECA3x41LcPgLJDBu/5ylAQ1XjHLyJXnqByxtmrhctSVk@pbXcMA@uGoZV@DCDc5RvkNuheJY7W8Gag13La0vJSybcRnZ0v9cwFw8cgdyCpx3LXR7ajMDnnLFHUkNFyy3uIUsRBF6CdPMvlOhqtAf6EYXn4EBCZmqILSs3WIrnyAE9RMEeeCDW3cjywiGFiYNm1SxdYQSqytBuCm5rGxRjSyV8W17dfUNTW7OFgq6u/Zla3s3V7LEuOxVbthl8t5TmRH2w/170FeGmxYa6lLdnNA7TmgsDyy@lFFEUrWPS9IEalOzm2XC7uS0Icr@pKMM5qqc@35lHsvwrRssmL5CtC5OTHrrfr8HP/r@kHPec9Spq@NUZr2COjkDaLM0hkkPj//8YBHRt5QrxP6SQq7347bWzJRin5nPod62Dk8lIsfpvkqj5NrIisOtpj09LwduQT0h0RJ8FacYGgLCiKsPmJLagC3wV0BbokGYFGQB8iEu@WHNZNEJzI4XEf5rkPXNCvIqidMEEsN0JSwSbynuFUnFCLBjQPG8ebkKFhY1pY4uoDsI0lUcHhQoCU9Bgxyv7qYzID2bqXWKwDunig0KklrUuAhTgMCi@UKATKAkvGyWQVPKpFEwfzF/ierhCu4JTBmJI1AXyWvsY5GjsxlyRyXBX9CHkHpHQiAhzOQ@xBpgn5FNugJFAmaRgidTGpMZo7QMrhAM6MAAhldFv6j78X7hx7hD2bLOkd9iJCpn5vIgzOXersBX/uI65JA4xLgYkClv@3n42nMqLin72V5VdqoS5L9IyCeo6SK3Q8BDTLZxRV9KLjrUr7kpCebrmgvXjZvKbwreJXV9Gn/NLnKbqubIYnXfvqdQ28/VZNx@40LgpEKHN5Yv68H1VAMJY1zNUCZRPo140z7tA7UjRKer@a/qXuY4Ywb5caivm1PGrrguoI@aQfJZAklWz75M3dKXM1GEpzagNNWhjecwMAtyyWdQupiNLfbteXPLHmRnxcnzBPm6@G2EyvEzToClI2i8RZMm1D6JzptC1Le6z6MxF5fSFe0Mr1bCrJKCkiB9Yj5ZYAaDFAkNmHPlEVvAfC7zKkyOl5SleCsfD6pkquPmYFRdBMqv@OT3gsbWySkv3sunIXn3Xin/5NmjU1lSopTQWYJXFtcucjBpk4ODyWQgCRSjXOdcQNhBJaU/dNVQ7SCrSEYzJhWrTj9UgZifCDr/@de/nXLe0VUGlOflOkMV7LLKAGqaul1a5D0VhAourRIp5UB@VaTLY0ozt9vrV4d@InrpTPgtF40Qpsdpyqm54FX3jn35TRYUy3yrpXuPzVc4hTyXb8y9Gt2x64fhxNc93L3O27022et0NB94WNA4G@7lz2osafiB@T1Kk@EeFzCDTgSUrXveLk6h4iRFyPnQBO8kacdZgsifj6ODYetoRo4swtAr8KYV6FcWH@rLQjKuHKMmGI8urinKP0iTGz2CA2jl1OqzTqcDiZPcP33wkEAKhUfHXsZweVofgtPAYgO6nyfW6/zSO/SrFMaKODgU5Eg6Gnx9XCm9KdClo6@PB@XFhAqCWN7Rb7jEpqgScL9zQcg22lvolwR@8fDlX5@clQQupUPjtvITtCjdmzmO8@HNd/vffXvQ74y6H@BRL/w@9Fr/BQ)

Comment: 10 bytes: `q@#@8*1-[.` It could be 8 bytes with `q@#@5*[.`, but hitting `[` or `]` with a `0` goes into an endless loop, since it doesn't move the pointer. Not sure if that is intentional or not.

Comment: Also, this is a really neat looking language! Just so you know, you could check out [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) to host your Python interpreter online. I use it for [my](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com/) [languages](https://brainbox.pythonanywhere.com/), and it's also used for [Vyxal](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/) and [Rattle](https://rattleinterpreter.pythonanywhere.com/).

Comment: @AaroneousMiller The endless loop thing is intentional, just another edgecase you have to constantly keep track of, or else your program breaks... I'll check out pythonanywhere, thx!

Comment: lol, I love it!

Comment: 8 bytes by terminating with an error (lol) `q@#@2$]]`

Comment: @MannyQueen It's not supposed to do that D:
Now the question is: if I fix the interpreter, can I still use your solution? I'm not entirely sure...

Answer (score 3):

## [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/programs/unlambda/), 15 bytes

```
``c``@?1i `c`|i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K83LScxNSkn8/z8hITkhwcHeMFMByKjJ/P/fAAA)

Comment: This sent me down a bit of a rabbit hole of Unlambda. What a wild language!

Comment: @Mayube mission successful ;)

Answer (score 3):

### [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
,.[-[->>]<++<]>>>[+[.]]
```

I ran it [here](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LC5bLVstPj5dPCsrPF0+Pj5bK1suXV0=) (Uses negative cells, get around this by adding  a << to the beginning)

I used modulus 2 instead of subtracting 48 to differentiate 0 and 1 which cuts down some characters. I also copied and did modulus at the same time.

Old answers:

```
,.[->+>+<<]>[-[<<]>[.]>-]

,.[->+>+<<]>[-[>>]>[.]<<<-]
```

Comment: Site is no longer available (also, i think you mean adding a `>>` to the beginning to avoid negative cells). You can save a byte by doing `[+.-]` instead

Answer (score 3):

## [StupidStackLanguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StupidStackLanguage), 5 bytes

```
htxux
```

[Try it online!](https://lebster.xyz/projects/stustala#61c549555763ef239c4c62db)

Answer (score 3):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 12 bytes (2×6=12 codels)

```
tavnsJ dl jj
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJwNikEKgCAURO8y6xH8BWVeRV2EGQRlgbWK7t6f1Zs38yKfS4EPwVIGCkf2dIlBJkpHNROdikS0csHDGANi3w5lsRptpWX4dd5bIbZ6PbduNla9xir4fukuGc0)

As a grid:

```
tavnsj
 dl jj
```

As an image:

[image]

There was an existing [answer with 12 codels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229142/78410), but I got this independently. Any smaller image size is likely not possible, though ascii-piet encoding allows to omit trailing black cells on each line (which makes the linked answer 11 bytes) and therefore may allow for a bit more optimization.

#### How it works

If the input is 1:

[image]

```
      InN        [1]
Loop: DP+        []   (rotate right once)
      OutN       []   (stack underflow, ignored)
      Push1      [1]
      Dup        [1 1]
      Goto Loop
      DP+        [1]  (rotate right once)
      OutN       []   (print 1)
      Push1      [1]
      Dup        [1 1]
      Goto Loop ...
```

If the input is 0:

[image]

```
InN    [0]
DP+    []   (go straight through)
Push1  [1]
Not    [0]
OutN   []   (print 0)
HALT
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
{x}{ \x}/.1:0
```

[(Don't) Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyrrqitVoipqNXXM7QyAAAjKQRV)

The web interpreter does support stdin (via a popup prompt), and entering a 0 will print a single 0. But entering a 1 will hang the entire tab.

We need an unbounded loop, which means either `m m/` or a recursive function. The latter being `{x o/ \x}@.1:0` is 1 byte longer than the above.

```
{x}{ \x}/.1:0  full program
          1:0  read stdin as a single list of bytes (= single string)
         .     eval it
{ }{   }/      while loop:
 x               while the value is truthy,
     \x          debug-print the value (print with newline) and return it unchanged
```

If the input is 0, the loop runs zero times and the resulting value 0 is implicitly printed. If the input is 1, the loop runs forever, printing `1\n` repeatedly.

Comment: an ATO link is useful for showing output: [`{x}{ \x}/.1:0`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700Oz4vPW_BgqWlJWm6FmurK2qrFWIqavX1DK0MIGJQqQULDSEMAA)

Comment: also, `{x}( \)/.1:0` seems to work

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
WaPaa
```

In pseudocode:

```
while(a)
    print(a)
autoprint(a)
```

`a` is the first command-line argument. (The OP commented on the sandbox post that this was an acceptable way to take input, even though Pip *is* capable of taking input from stdin.)

Comment: WaPaa. I love these weird types of languages because when you put them into TTS programs they have a conniption.

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://gist.github.com/dloscutoff/254267bce8cb09f009ad), 36 bytes

This is a language that I'm basing [an upcoming challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7312/16766) on. The spec in the challenge doesn't include the `disp` function, but the reference implementation does.

```
(d M(q((x)(i x(i(disp x)0(M x))0))))
```

Defines a function `M` that takes an argument `x` (the closest that the language has to input). If `x` is falsey, we return `0`, which is printed. If `x` is truthy, we want to display `x` and then recurse. There isn't any equivalent to Common Lisp's `progn` in the language, so the best way to do this is to use the `disp` call as the condition of an `i`f. The result is falsey, thus putting the recursive call `(M x)` in the else branch.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sisi](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Sisi), 22 bytes

Sisi doesn't have any way to take user input, so the number is expected to be stored in the variable `x` (presumably on line 1).

```
2 print x
3 jumpif x 2
```

Pretty straightforward: print the number, and keep doing so as long as it's 1.

Answer (score 2):

## Beam, <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 13 bytes

```
rSn(`)>@<
H@<
```

Try it in the [online interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57190/42545)! (Warning: it may crash your browser with an input other than 0.)

Beam is a 2D language, based on the concept of a beam of light moving through the 2D source code. Beam is oriented around two main memory values: one held by the beam, and one called the "store". Here are the commands used, in order:

- `r` - Set the beam to the next ASCII code in the input. (48 for `0`, 49 for `1`)
- `S` - Set the store to the beam.
- `n` - If beam != store, point the beam downward. Does nothing the first time.
- `(` and `)` - If store != 0, point the beam right/left, respectively.
- `` ` `` - Decrement the store by 1.

Now, the beam enters `` (`) `` from the left, and bounces back and forth until the store reaches 0. If the store's initial value is 48 (`0`), it will exit to the left, traveling through these chars:

- `n` - If beam != store, point the beam downward. This time, since the beam is 48 and the store is 0, it does its job.
- `<` - Unconditionally point the beam to the left.
- `@` - Output the beam as an ASCII character. Prints `0`.
- `H` - Halt the program.

However, if the store's initial value is 49 (`1`), it exits the loop to the right, and runs through this code:

- `>` - Unconditionally point the beam to the right.
- `@` - Output the beam as an ASCII character. Prints `1`.
- `<` - Unconditionally point the beam to the left.
- `@` - Output the beam as an ASCII character. Prints `1`.
- `>` ...

...and so on until the end of time (or until your browser crashes).

Thanks to @MickyT for this awesome layout!

P.S. If you want to learn more about Beam, check out and vote on [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59176/42545)!

Comment: +1 I like it, didn't think I could shorten it, but here's a slightly shorter version.  2 Lines `rSn(\`)>@<` and `H@<` for 13

Comment: @MickyT Holy cow, that's brilliant! I'll update in a sec

Answer (score 2):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), <s>30</s> 19 bytes

Similar method to my [BF answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62784/34718). Input and print, subtract the `0` (the source's last byte) from the input, so cell is 0 or 1. Loop printing if input cell is 1. Tested on my [Python interpreter](http://ideone.com/L2byRe).

```
,.<[->-<]>[<<.>>]10
```

You can also run it on [TIO](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/X0fPJlrXTtcm1i7axkbPzi7W0OD/fwMA).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> <s>73</s> <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```
x=prompt()==1;j=a=>{if(x)setTimeout(j,9);console.log(+x)};j()
```

This program **doesn't** crash your web browser!

Explanation:

```
x = prompt() == 1;             // this makes sure input is 1 or not while defining
j = a => {                     // es6 arrow function
  if (x)                        // if x is 1
    setTimeout(j, 9);            // make sure to do this function again in 9ms
  console.log(+x);              // log the number
};
j();                           // call j
```

Comment: Better version: `x=prompt()==1;j=()=>{if(x)requestAnimationFrame(j);console.log(x?1:0)};j()`

Comment: Even better, replace `j=()=>` with `j=a=>`

Comment: Actually, using `x=prompt();` is shorter, but you have an `x==1?1:0` that could just be `x`. That leaves `x=prompt();j=a=>{if(x==1)requestAnimationFrame(j);console.log(x)};j()` at 69 bytes. However, instead of using requestAnimationFrame you could use a setTimeout, which is shorter and leads to `x=prompt();j=a=>{if(x==1)setTimeout(j,10);console.log(x)};j()` at 69. Oh crap! That would mean that JS beats Stack! D:

Comment: Haha. The reason I use `x==1?1:0` is so that if the user inputs `"true"` it counts as 0.

Comment: (oh my, it's liam4! hey!) But you don't need to. The only inputs needed 1 and 0.

Comment: Great work! I think `+x` will work in place of `x?1:0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Stuck), 9 Bytes

Stuck has a while loop function (which I never added to the docs on Esolangs, but it has existed for a little over 2 months) which makes this possible. It wasn't before this as far as I know :P.

```
ip"1="'ph
```

Comment: Dammit I was trying to make a truth machine in Stuck but couldn't figure out how to do it without a while loop

Comment: @quartata Sorry about that :P Whenever I get enough free time I will update the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

### Brainfuck, 54 bytes

```
+++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]>>>,.[>+<<[>>-<<-]>>>+<<-]>[>.<]
```

**Explanation:**

`+++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]>>>` Set a register to 48 (ASCII 0), using multiplication to reduce the byte count (3*4*4), then set the pointer to the next instruction

`,.` Receive and print a line of input

`[>+<<[>>-<<-]>>>+<<-]`Set the next register to be a numerical value, and the one after to represent the ascii output value

`>` Move the data pointer to the numerical register

`[>.<]` While the numerical register is not 0, print the ascii register

Comment: I already have a [shorter BF program](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62784/34718), but just so you know, `48` can be made shorter. See [this helpful page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#48).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I didn't see your program before I posted mine, must have missed it when scrolling through.

Comment: Try running the code snippet contained in the question.

Answer (score 2):

## brainfuck, 20 bytes

```
,[.>+<-[-[>]<++<-]>]
```

This requires an interpreter that exits with an error upon stepping out of bounds with `<` (such as [this one](http://mazonka.com/brainf/bfdebug.html)). Stepping over the left edge in case of an even value was the easiest way I found to do a parity test. I wouldn't be surprised if it could be a couple of bytes shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>51</s> 45 bytes

```
readline()>"0"?while 2>1 print(1)end:print(0)
```

Read a string from STDIN. If it's lexicographically larger than the string `"0"` then print 1 forever, otherwise print 0 and we're done.

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Sp3000!

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 44 bytes

```
@set/p n=
:a
@echo %n%
@if %n%==1 goto :a
```

### Explanation

- `set /p` reads from stdin into a variable
- `:a` is a GOTO marker, because batch does not have while loops

The rest should be obvious: output the variable `n` and if `n` is 1, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

### Common Lisp, 30

```
(do((x(read)))((=(print x)0)))
```

Common Lisp's **print** function returns the object that was printed.
This reads a value from the user, then prints the value until the return value of the call to **print** returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, <s>54</s> 48 Bytes

```
Sub f(u):Do:Debug.Print u:Loop While u>0:End Sub
```

Look Guys, VBA can fit on one line(<s>*almost*</s>) and be hard(*ish*) to read like all the other Languages.

`Debug.Print` could be `Msgbox` but I feel that isn't the Spirit of the challenge and you really don't want Never ending pop-ups

Old Code

```
Sub f(u):Do:Debug.Print u:If u=0 Then End
Loop:End Sub
```

Comment: Using `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` as your input and running in the Immediate Window, you can reduce to **31** bytes: `?[A1]:Do Until[A1]=0:?[A1]:Loop`

Comment: For sure. Any of my VBA answers are designed not to run in immediate and do not use sheets. VBA can for sure be shortened by using those methods and I encourage you to explore the possibilities. But at the time there were few to no VBA responses so I limited myself to Subs only.

Answer (score 2):

### FORTH, <s>44 bytes</s> <s>39 bytes</s> 31 bytes

**Edit:**

As suggested by @Nate Eldredge, we can shorten the code, if we allow extra spaces in the output. This program is 31 bytes long:

```
: P BEGIN DUP . ?DUP 0= UNTIL ;
```

Sample run:

```
1 P
0 P
```

**First version:**

```
: P BEGIN DUP 48 + EMIT ?DUP 0= UNTIL ;
```

Sample run:

```
1 P
0 P
```

Explanation:

```
We expect the value 'b' of 0 or 1 on the stack.

: P       -- beginning a word P                          ( b ) 
BEGIN     -- starting a loop                             ( b )
DUP 48 +  -- creating an ASCII code for the character    ( b  b+48 )
EMIT      -- echoing the character                       ( b )
?DUP      -- dup'ing the value if non-zero               ( 1  1 ) or ( 0 )
0=        -- testing if the value is zero                ( 1 FALSE) or ( TRUE )
UNTIL     -- end of the loop if true                     ( 1 ) or ( - )
;         -- finishing the word
```

If I take the challenge seriously, FORTH has Standard I/O capabilities, but it is natural in FORTH to take the input from the stack.

If I use the STDIO feature, the code looks like this (44 bytes)

```
: P KEY BEGIN DUP EMIT DUP 48 = UNTIL DROP ;
```

Sample run:

```
P
```

(Note, that in my environment the standard input was buggy)

Comment: My FORTH is rusty, but wouldn't it be easier and shorter to use `.` instead of `48 + EMIT`?

Comment: @NateEldredge `.` puts an extra space after the number, otherwise it's OK. I've read in some answers that it may be acceptable. If that's the case we can shorten the code. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### MIPS asm, 24 bytes

```
main:
li $v0, 5  # load read int
syscall  # exec read int, stores value in $v0
move $a0, $v0  # store in $a0
li $v0, 1  # load print int
loop:
syscall  # print $a0
bgtz $a0, loop  # loop while $a0 is greater than zero
```

Had to learn MIPS recently, might as well do something fun with it.

Answer (score 2):

### C, 35 chars

```
main(c){for(gets(&c);c%puts(&c););}
```

This is even hackier than [cbojar's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62885/3544), from which I copied the abuse of the parameter `c` (`int` used as `char[4]`), along with the reliance on little-endian.

`puts` returns a non-negatve number on success, which (on my Linux/gcc4.8.2) happens to be the number of bytes printed, which happens to be 2. `c%2` tests if `c` is odd, which is true for `'1'` and false for `'0'`.

Answer (score 2):

### [O](http://github.com/phase/o), 14 bytes

```
i{1{1o1}w}{0o}?
```

[O](http://o.readthedocs.org) is a work-in-progress language with loads of commands and an interpreter written in "APL-style C", which means incomprehensible code.

`i`     Get input as String

`{`     Start a CodeBlock (like ruby)

`1`    Push 1 to the stack

`{`    Start a CodeBlock

`1`   Push 1 to the stack

`o`   Pop the stack and print it

`1`   Push 1 to the stack

`}`    Push the CodeBlock to the stack

`w`    Do the CodeBlock on the top of the stack while the value under it is true. (Pops them both.)

`}`     Push the CodeBlock to the stack

`{`     Start a CodeBlock

`0`    Push 0 to the stack

`o`    Pop the stack and print it

`}`     Push the CodeBlock to the stack

`?`     If the 3rd down value in the stack is truthy, do the CodeBlock 2nd down in the stack, otherwise do the CodeBlock on the top. (Pops the first 3 values on the stack.)

Comment: "APL-style C" - you mean nightmares?

Comment: @Mego yep, [pretty much](https://github.com/phase/o/blob/master/o.c)

Comment: I think you're being unfair to APL.

Comment: @ThomasKwa it's a [direct quote](https://github.com/phase/o/issues/16).

Comment: @Hipe that is horrible. must it be golfed?

Answer (score 2):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py), 23

This version doesn't terminate after the zero is printed, but that should be alright:

```
..}0
../\//
>0
}0
+O
+O
```

Old version:

```
}0@0
\\
../\+O
>0\/+O
@0
```

It doesn't add a newline between each `1`, but whatevs.

Comment: You need to terminate if your language is at all capable of terminating.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2- 64 bytes

```
x=input()
if x==0:print"0"
elif x==1:
 while True: print"1"
```

Comment: A trick you can exploit in Python is that `0` is the same as `False` and anything but `0`, including `1`, is `True`. This generally holds in most programming languages

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 24 bytes

```powershell
'for(){1}'*"$args"+0|iex
```

Generate expression as string and pass it to `Invoke-Expression` (`eval`).

It casts `$args` array to string with `""`, then multiplication sign casts it to `int` and string `for(){1}` is repeated `int` times (1 or 0 - empty string). Then we add `0` to this string, which will be cast to a string also.

Resulting string expression (`for(){1}0` or `0`) is then piped to `Invoke-Expression`, resulting either in endless loop outputting `1` or one-time output of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Detour](http://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html), 2 bytes

```
,~
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=fiw%3D)

`,` will print a value then push it to the next cell.

`~` is a filter, so it will push a value IFF it is greater than 0.

Cells wrap around the edges.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 4 bytes

```
`GtD
```

#### Relevant MATL features <sup>*</sup>

To explain the code, the following MATL features need to be presented first.

- `` ` `` ...`]` is a "do ...while" loop. The top of the stack is consumed at the end of each iteration, and used to decide whether to go on with a new iteration or not. The last `]` can be omitted if it's at the end of the program (loops are implicitly closed).
- `G` works as follows:

  - When there has been no user-input it does nothing;
  - When there has been one user-input it pushes it onto the stack
  - When there has been more than one user-input it takes a numeric argrument and pushes one of those user-inputs onto the stack
- `t` by default duplicates the top element of the stack
- `D` by default displays the top element of the stack, and consumes it.
- If a function requires more inputs than currently are in the stack, user-input is implicitly triggered. The entered elements are placed below the current bottom of the stack.

#### Code explanation

`` ` `` enters the loop. At the first iteration, `G` does nothing. `t` implicitly asks for user input and duplicates it. `D` displays and consumes the duplicate, leaving the original input on the stack. If this input is `0` the loop is exited and the program finishes (a single `0` has been displayed). If the input is `1`, control goes to the beginning of the loop again. Now `G` pastes the input, `t` duplicates it, `D` displays and consumes that duplicate, and again there's a `1` to be used as loop condition, so the loop begins again, indefinitely (an infinite number of `1` is displayed).

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> at the time of writing. The behaviour of `G` has changed since then: `G` now triggers implicit input when there has been no user-input yet. However, this doesn't affect the code, which works the same. The only difference is that in the first iteration the implicit input is now triggered by `G`,  not by `t`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 87 bytes

```
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a[0]);main(a[0].split("0"));}}
```

(has output to STDERR, but that should not matter)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is valid. The rules state that the program must infinitely run unless killed or out of memory. This will cause a stack overflow, since Java doesn't have tail call recursion optimization.

Comment: Yes, for the standard JVM; but there the size of the stack depends on the memory allocated. If the memory allocated by `-Xss` is large enough, it will run arbitrarily long (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734108/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-the-java-call-stack). The stack overflow therefore is just the visible result of the program being out of memory.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't consider `-Xss`. Upvoted, and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure, but might there exist even some other JavaVMs that handle this more efficiently?

Comment: I'm not aware of any JVM implementations that do tail call recursion optimization. I know Oracle HotSpot doesn't, and I doubt Excelsior does.

Comment: Program arguments are **not** STDIN!

Comment: @SeanBean "take input from STDIN or an acceptable alternative" - [command-line arguments are an acceptable input method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2449/45941).

Comment: The boring thing about challenges like this is there is really only one good answer per language. You can't get shorter than this which is really boring... I downvoted

Comment: maybe downvote the challenge if you don't like it, instead of this particular Java answer? Not that I mind but you could reach a larger audience there... downvoting because you believe an answer is the shortest kind of defeats the purpose of codegolf??

Comment: A stack overflow is a form of memory outage: there is no more place in the stack memory for another stack frame.

Answer (score 2):

## [HALT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HALT), 49 bytes

```
1 IF '0' 2 ELSE 3
2 TYPE '0';HALT
3 TYPE '1';SET 1
```

Pretty simple. If input is one go to `3`, output `1`, set the pointer to `1` so the program never ends. If input is output `0`, print, then halt.

[Online interpreter](http://vihanserver.tk/p/langs/HALT/) (Firefox only)

Comment: such amazing much wow where's rightgoat

Comment: @Seadrus ---I ate him---. I mean, he'll be coming soon

Comment: No he won't, you're the only goat left ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <s>56</s> 52 Bytes

I know that [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62866/41019) in 70 Bytes exists, but its author doesn't look like he's updating it when someone point out an improvement.

```lua
if io.read'*n'>0then::a::print"1"goto a end print"0"
```

**Old 56 bytes solution**

```lua
if io.read()=="1"then while""do print"1"end end print"0"
```

Nothing special here, just using the fact that `""` evaluates to `true` to save a byte on the infinite loop. Parenthesis for functions parameters aren't mandatory when they only take a single string, which is not stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

## [Shtriped](https://github.com/HelkaHomba/shtriped), 33 bytes

```
e :
t :
.
 d :
 i :
 p :
 .
.
p :
```

This prints the `0` or the infinite stream of `1`'s without any trailing newlines or spaces.

Explanation:

```
e :  \ initialize a variable named ":"
t :  \ prompt for integer input, storing the result in :
.    \ define a function named "." that will only return if : is 0 (the next 4 indented lines are part the function)
 d : \ decrement : if : is positive, else return immediately
 i : \ : must have been 1 to reach here and was just decremented, so increment back to 1
 p : \ print :, which we know is 1
 .   \ recursively call ., endlessly looping
.    \ call . initially
p :  \ if . terminated this line will finally be run, printing : which we know is 0
```

Answer (score 2):

### [BASTARD](https://github.com/shakna-israel/bastard), 83 bytes

```
{{fi in 0{!b {= {t 0} ‘1’} {(o <> {{fi out ‘1’}{o}}){o}}{fi out ‘0’}}}}
```

**Note:** This language is not qualified. Mostly because I'm still designing it. I just wanted to test drive it against some puzzles.

**Explanation:**

**fi in** copies the input into the **0** place on the Variable Stack.

**!b** is a basic if statement to check if its a "1" or not.

If it is, we just use **fi out** to print our "0".

Otherwise, we define a new function called **o** that prints a "1", and then calls itself again.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. This is a great first answer, +1. Your language looks interesting; once you've got enough reputation you could get help developing it on Chat.

Answer (score 2):

## [NTFJ](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/NTFJ), 27 bytes

```
:*:##~~~~~#@|########@|($~^
```

An online interpreter can be found [here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/NTFJ/).

NTFJ is an esoteric programming language, made by user @ConorO'Brien, that is intended to be a Turing tarpit. It is stack-based, and pushes bits to the stack, which can be later coalesced to an 8-bit number.

- The only pushable values are 0 with `~` and 1 with `#`.
- The only manipulations possible to the actual values of the stack are to wrap eight bits into a byte with `@`, and to NAND with `|`.
- The only logic command is IF with `()`, but combined with JUMP `^`, it can be used to create loops.

Thus, it's quite difficult to manipulate values to do your bidding.

#### How it works

```
                               Implicit input: byte 48 for 0 or 49 for 1.
:*:                            Duplicate the top item, pop/output, and duplicate again.
   ##~~~~~#@|                  Push 193 and perform NAND.
             ########@|        Push 255 and perform NAND.
                               These two operations change 48 to 0 and 49 to 1.
                       (       If the top item is not 0:
                        $       Pop the top item.
                         ~^     Push 0 and jump to that instruction.
                               This effectively creates a while loop that loops the entire program.
```

Comment: I believe removing the last paren should still work.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks, it does!

Answer (score 2):

## [Beatnik](http://esolangs.org/wiki/beatnik), 26 bytes

```
J ZD ZD JA K ZZZZJ Z JJ MF
```

[Try it online](http://beatnik.tryitonline.net/#code=SiBaRCBaRCBKQSBLIFpaWlpKIFogSkogTUY&input=MA)

An explanation

```
Words    Scores   Action
J        8        Get character value from input
ZD       12       Duplicate TOS
ZD       12       Duplicate TOS
JA       9        Output TOS character
K ZZZZJ  5 48     Push 48 (char 0) onto stack
z        10       Pop 2 from stack and subtract
JJ MF    16 (7)   If not zero skip back 7 words
```

Of course something like the following, while still not making sense, looks more like what you would expect for a Beatnik program.

```
Shall falsey determine truths? We **WithoutAWarningAboutMemoryUse** printed infinitely yeas!
```

Comment: The last one mostly makes sense, except for `He quackpizzled?` :)

Comment: @ETHproductions Yea, try to find a word that is SORTAWORDLIKEWITHABIGNUMBER and still fits gets difficult :)  Will have a play and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @ETHproductions  That's a bit better now

Answer (score 2):

## [UGL](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language), 6 bytes

```
il$o:o
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aWwkbzpv&input=MQ)

How it works:

```
i       #stack.push(input)
 l  :   #while stack.peek():
  $     #    stack.dup()
   o    #    print(stack.pop())
      o #print(stack.pop())
```

Answer (score 2):

## [WistfulC](https://github.com/nazek42/wistful-c), 141 bytes

This C has seen better days.

```
if only int n were 0...
wish for "%d",&n upon a star
someday !n... wish "1" upon a star
*sigh*
wish "0" upon a star
if wishes were horses...
```

Obviously not competitive, but then neither is this language.

Rough translation to regular C:

```
int n = 0;
scanf("%d", &n);
while (n) {
    puts("1");
}
puts("0");
exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Silicon](http://github.com/m654z/Silicon), 3 bytes

```
I[]
```

Explanation:

```
I          Get input
[          While the top of the stack is 1
           Implicit output
]          End while
           Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## MarioLang, 25 bytes

```
   >:<
   "==
 ;[!:
===#=
```

Comment: Why is this non-competing? Just FYI: "Non-competing" generally means "Uses language features that are newer than the challenge" or "Used to be valid but the rules changed".

Comment: I mean that I am not using this code to win this challenge. but upvotes are free!

Comment: That's not what non-competing means here. Also, [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/62933#62933) predates yours and is a lot shorter.

Comment: @Dennis You're correct.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan I was just aware that there was a shorter one and said "non-competing".

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 34 bytes

```
<?for($f=fgetc(STDIN);$f;?>1<?)?>0
```

Wanted to try to get rid of the print but not sure it's worth it since you have to reintroduce the `<?` tags

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL 23 bytes

No `STDIN` here so a hard-coded variable.

`DECLARE @ INT =1;` or `DECLARE @ INT =0;`

and the truth machine is

`l:PRINT @ IF(1=@)GOTO l`

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>41</s>, 40 bytes

```
main(c){for(c=getchar();putchar(c)&1;);}
```

Reads a single character from `stdin`, writes to `stdout`.

This version is 1 byte longer than [feersum's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62761), but removes his/her assumptions on`stdin`.

Comment: Would `putchar(c)&1` work?

Comment: Yes, you are right! One byte saved, thanks @Dennis.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>143</s> <s>141</s> <s>125</s> 88 bytes

```
interface T {static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a[0]);main(a[0].split("0"));}}
```

## Ungolfed Test Code

```
interface T {

    static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.print(a[0]);
        main(a[0].split("0"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's 143 characters.

Comment: Why did you even check?

Comment: I'm using a [userscript](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design) for PPCG, and it tells me how many bytes there are. (You should totally use it, it's worth it)

Comment: Ahh ok. It's shorter now anyway :P

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, 34 Bytes

```
repeat print(arg[2])until arg[2]<1
```

arg[2] contains the first command line argument, (arg[1] contains the filename)

Give an input through the command line, and it shall spam it if it's 1, or once if it's not.

Simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 5 Bytes

```
,.[.]
```

I/O is as 0x00 / 0x01 bytes.

I just think it's a neat thing.

Answer (score 2):

### [Copy](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/copy), <s>67</s> 59 bytes

My new esolang :D

```
getch a
add b a
add b -48
print a
skip b
skip 1
copy -4 0 1
```

Explanation:

```
getch a     Take input in variable 'a'
add b a     Set 'b' to 'a'
add b -48   Substract 48 from 'b'
print a     Print 'a'
skip b      Skip the copy if 'a' is not zero
skip 1      ^
copy -4 0 1 Copy the code block from the print to this instruction after this instruction
```

Comment: protip: *subtract

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon No

Answer (score 2):

## [Crystal](http://crystal-lang.org/), <s>48</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

<s>`y=gets;y=="0\n"&&(p 0;exit);y=="1\n"&&loop{p 1}`</s>
<s>`y=gets;y=="0\n"&&(p 0;exit);loop{p 1}`</s>
`y=gets;y=="0\n"&&(p 0;1/0);loop{p 1}`

Edit: Shaved off 10 bytes because the post doesn't specify what should happen on invalid input (like `2`). If it does and I misunderstood, let me know.

Edit: Shaved off 1 byte by dying with an error instead of normal exit.

Crystal is statically typed, so I couldn't just do `gets.chomp` (`gets` can return `nil`, and `nil` doesn't have `chomp`). The alternative was `gets.try &.chomp`, but that takes much more space than just having the newlines.

In Crystal (and Ruby) you can do something like `puts 0 if y=="0\n"`, however you can also shave off 2 bytes by doing `y=="0\n"&&puts 0` as the `&&` operator returns the last object it tests for truthiness.

`loop` is a method in the standard lib that infinitely runs the block. It's a much shorter way of writing `while true;CODE;end`.

`p` prints the result of `.inspect` on its arguments to the output. Here I abuse it as a shorter `puts` because for numbers it'll just return the number.

Answer (score 2):

## Valve scripting language, 38 bytes

```
alias 0 echo 0
alias 1 "echo 1;wait;1"
```

This defines two commands, `0` and `1`. Type `0` into the console for the zero case, and `1` for the 1 case.

Comment: Could I just try this in half life's console, or do I need the source SDK?

Comment: @Pavel I tested it on the TF2 console, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

## Underload, 16 bytes

```
((1)S:^)~^:^(0)S
```

Underload has no way to take input from standard input. The most natural way to take input is therefore from the initial stack: `()` for 1, `(!())` for 0 (this is the [normal way to represent numbers in Underload](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload#Numbers)).

Here are Try It Online links for [0](http://underload.tryitonline.net/#code=KCEoKSkoKDEpUzpeKX5eOl4oMClT&input=) and for [1](http://underload.tryitonline.net/#code=KCkoKDEpUzpeKX5eOl4oMClT&input=&debug=on) (be prepared to kill this one quickly; the infinite loop runs very quickly and will spam up your browser window).

This program didn't need much effort to golf; the most idiomatic way to do things is almost the shortest (I just had to be careful not to let the input get buried too far on the stack). It's easiest to read if I translate the code to a hypothetical functional language:

```
function x(y)
    print(1)
    x(x)
end
x = x^(input)
x(x)
print(0)
```

The only weird thing happening here is being able to exponentiate functions, but it's a fairly easy-to-understand operation; for example, raising a function `f` to the power 3 would produce `f` compose `f` compose `f`, i.e. `lambda x.f(f(f(x)))`. Raising a function to the power 1 does nothing (just like if you'd raised an integer to the power 1); and raising a function to the power 0 gives you the identity function (just like raising a number to the power 0 gives you 1). Actually, the integers in Underload are defined in terms of their effect exponentiating functions, rather than the other way round; the operation is fundamental enough to Underload that you use it to construct most flow control.

Answer (score 2):

### Jelly, 3 bytes

```
Ṅ¹¿
```

If reading from STDIN is absolutely required:

```
ƈOḂṄ¹¿`
```

I'm not sure which since ["Jelly's main input method is via command line arguments, although reading input from STDIN is also possible."](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Your second version can also be [`ƓṄ¹¿`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39s8sOdLYd2Htr//78hAA), where it reads a line instead of a single character.

Answer (score 2):

### SmileBASIC, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
INPUT N@L?N?N/N
GOTO@L
```

Ends the program with a divide by 0 error.

If this isn't allowed, here's a 23 byte solution:

```
INPUT N@L?N
IF N GOTO@L
```

Answer (score 2):

## WireWorld (It doesnt have a scoring method yet :\)

```
 ████ █ <= this pixel will be the input. if it is a electron head (1), 
█    █     It will loop forever as 1. if its a wire (0), it will do nothing.
█ ██ █
 ██ █
  ██
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 7 bytes

Golfed 4 bytes off [my example program](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BitCycle#Truth-machine)!

```
?~<
!~+
```

Provide input as `0` or `1` on the command-line. The `-s` or `-p` debug options are recommended, especially when dealing with infinite output.

#### Explanation

BitCycle is a 2D language that works by moving bits around a playfield. Commands used in this program are:

- `?` puts input bit(s) onto the playfield, moving east
- `~` duplicates and negates a bit, turning the original right and the negated copy left
- `<` sends bits westward
- `+` turns 1-bits right and 0-bits left
- `!` outputs bits

The input hits the first `~`. A negated copy turns left (north) off the playfield and is discarded. The original bit turns right (south).

At the second `~`, the original bit turns west into the `!` and is output. A negated copy turns east.

If the original bit was `0`, the negated copy is `1`; it turns south at the `+`, goes off the playfield, and is discarded.

If the original bit was `1`, the negated copy is `0`; it turns north at the `+` and then west at the `<`. The `0` hits the first `~` again, where it turns right (north) off the playfield and is discarded. The negated copy (`1`) turns left (south), leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: Alternative 7 byter `?v~ newline !~+`

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
X
p|1
rip^
```

`r`eads a string and converts it to an `i`nteger. `|` tests for truthiness (1 is truthy, 0 is not) and mirrors horizontally if truthy (in that case moving to the 1). Otherwise, <s>we'll go to `0`, which pushes the 0,</s> we `p`rint implicit zero and e`X`it.

If the number was truthy (e.g. 1), we got mirrored to the `1`, which pushes a 1, `p`rints, and goes one cell up (`^`), going into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

### [MarioLANG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 11 bytes

```
;>:[<
=====
```

Explanation:

```
;        Get numerical input and save in current cell
 >       Move left (Required to make an infinite loop)
  :      Output the current cell
   [     Skip next command if cell is 0
    <    Move right
```

Basically, it loops infinitely unless input = 0

Answer (score 2):

## [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise), 3 bytes

```
[:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K88sTv3/P9oq9v///4YA)

Wise cannot actually output whenever you want, it only outputs the entire stack when the program terminates. So the solution to infinitely output is to simply infinitely fill the stack. When the program eventually halts (never), it will output the stack that, at that theoretical point in time, will have infinite values in it.

#### Explanation

```
[:]  Implicit input from command-line arg
[    If last value is != 0..
 :   ..Duplicate last value on stack
  ]  If last value is != 0, jump back to [
```

Given a non-zero number, will infinitely duplicate the input on the stack, after an infinite amount of time, will terminate and output the entire stack.

Given zero, jumps to the end of the program and immediately terminates, outputting the stack, which contains only the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 7 bytes

```
n:u[:u]
```

Explanation:

```
n        # take input
 :u      # duplicate it and print it
   [     # while the top of the stack is not 0...
    :u   # duplicate it and print it
   ]     # end loop
```

Comment: With the current version on TIO, this works `n[:u]` since the 0 on the stack prints when it exits.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) 2, <s>50</s> 39 bytes

Don't know why nobody mentioned I could just write `input()`

```
i=input()
while(int(i)):print 1
print 0
```

Very simple, if the input is `1`, will continuously print 1 and cannot reach the `print 0`. If it is `0`, the `while` will never fire.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSMzr0QjU1PTqqAIyFIw5ILQBv//GwIA)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using stdin instead of command line args.

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/vzwjMydVITOvoLREQ9OqoCgzr0TBkAtCG/z/bwgA), you don't need to cast the input to an `int` because the `input` function in Python 2 does `eval` on the input before returning. You also don't need parentheses around the `input` call.

Comment: Oh, actually... This code doesn't even work. Theoretically, it would work if infinite 1's were given as input, but that doesn't meet the spec. Since `while` is calling the `input` function every time, it will just print one 1 and then reach the end of the input and error. Your earlier solution with command line args did work, or you can assign the input to a variable before looping.

Comment: @LyricLy yeah, I tried that once. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 4 bytes

```
&:.%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X81KT/X/f0MA)

**Please note:** this answer is no longer valid with this particular interpreter. At the time of writing, the interpreter used had a quirk where trying to read more integers when there weren’t any would return the last integer. I believe that this was “fixed” in some interpreter update. (Thanks to @osuka_ for realizing that this answer no longer works)

#### Explanation:

```
&       Take number input
 :.     Duplicate and print input
   %    Mods the second from-the-top with the top number in the stack
        This means that if the top is 1, it will yield 0 % 1 = 0,
        But if it is a 0, it errors out and stops execution because you are
        trying to divide by 0
        
&       The program wraps back around if it didn't error, and the & takes
        the last number in the input if it has already taken them all, yielding
        the original 1 or 0
```

Coincidentally, this doesn't also work for `/`, because it strangely asks you what you want the answer to be.

Comment: The modulo trick is really clever. I love it.

Comment: This doesn't work - it prints `-1` instead of `1` after the first time.

Comment: @osuka_ I think it’s due to the interpreter being updated, unfortunately. I remember it used to be that reading an end of feed with `&` would give the last integer again (which would make this print 1). I think they changed it so it gives -1 on an EOF instead. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @MildlyMilquetoast No worries - The reason I stumbled upon this is that I was looking for other befunge answers, to see if anyone had already posted one identical (or very similar) to one I just wrote. I love the mod trick!

Comment: This can be fixed by adding two `!`s after the `&`

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 17 bytes

```
20 FD AE 20 9E B7 8A 09 30 20 D2 FF C9 30 D0 F9 60
```

[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"tm.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a4gnreKCTAg0v/JMND5YA=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"tm.prg"%7D%7D)

This is position independent code, you can enter it at any position in RAM and call it, so it doesn't need a load address. Assuming you put it at `C000` (that's the case in the online demo), call it like `sys49152,0` or `sys49152,1` -- any other input is *undefined*.

Explanation:

```
20 FD AE    JSR $AEFD    ; consume comma
20 9E B7    JSR $B79E    ; evaluate number, result in X
8A          TXA          ; transfer X to A
09 30       ORA #$30     ; convert to numeric character
20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2    ; output character
C9 30       CMP #$30     ; compare with '0' character
D0 F9       BNE *-5      ; not equal? Then jump back to output (-7)
60          RTS          ; return
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 26 bytes - Variation of [Solomon Ucko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46603/solomon-ucko)'s answer

*I find it weird how I can't comment, but I can [edit his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/62934#62934)...*

```js
for(;alert(i=prompt())|i;)
```

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, 6 Bytes

```
::n?!;
```

Input is assumed to be on the stack. It's duplicated twice, printed, and checked if it's non-zero. If it's non-zero, skip the end program command and loop around.

Note that this does not print any spacing between the 1s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
N
Count i while _%2-i%2+1 {
Write _
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXtVIN1PVSNtQoZorvCizBCjCVfv/vwEA)

This takes input through `N`, then prints the input `_` until the equation `_%2-i%2+1` is 0. This looks like:

```
48
  48%2-0%2+1 => 1
  48%2-1%2+1 => 0
  48%2-2%2+1 => 1
  48%2-3%2+1 => 0
49
  49%2-0%2+1 => 2
  49%2-1%2+1 => 1
  49%2-2%2+1 => 2
  49%2-3%2+1 => 1
```

This is shorter than the easy approach (39 bytes):

```
N
Write _
Count i while _%2 {
Write _
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@PK7wosyRVIZ7LOb80r0QhU6E8IzMHyFc1UqiGy9X@/28AAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 20 bytes

```
{do{print}while($0)}
```

This is the first thing I came up with. I tried to come up with something clever more clever but they were all longer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/OiW/uqAoM6@ktjwjMydVQ8VAs/b/fwMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forked](//git.io/Forked), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

<sup>-1 thanks to BMO</sup>

```
v >%&
$ |
>-:
  |
 %<
```

The IP path looks like this if the inputted integer is truthy:

```
v
|
>-v
  |
 %<
```

Upon hitting `%` (print as integer), it goes off the edge of the playing field and wraps around, running `>%` infinitely.

It takes this path if the inputted integer is falsy:

```
v >%&
| |
>-^
```

It prints `%` 0 and then exits `&`.

Answer (score 2):

## [ORK](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ORK), 395 bytes

```
There is such a thing as a m.
A m can p a word.

When a m is to p a word:
I have a scribe called W.
W is to write the word.
I have a linguist called C.
C's first operand is the word.
C's second operand is "1".
C is to compare.
If C says it's equal then I am to loop.

When this program starts:
I have a inputter called R.
I have a word called N.
R is to read N.
I have a m called M.
M is to p N.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC7bsMwDNz1FUSWbAKydis8ZUiGoIBnVmZioXqVlBv06x0qsA1vJO@Od2Tmn3n@GokJvIBMbgSEOvr0ABQtozWfEMFhgqLtM/NgjelHSg1smpo35MOcYcQ/0lYc@29SXQg0QG9Nv3Cf7CupAy27NkVQz8lLXTWdNd1R4O5ZZ7kQYxreOzZpg4Vc1vkOP5wOCi1uLseCTGpzhw4E/wV8VRn9ThjaqgRnwNioIeeynqYPECicH6yYVOQqu9t8KlOtxGvS2@6KlmydX625LTmY8N1vvLiSLtZctjde7TyfXg)

---

Here's the ungolfed version, which is not a whole lot different:

```
There is such a thing as a truth machine.
A truth machine can process a word.

When a truth machine is to process a word:
There is a scribe called Keymaker.
Keymaker is to write the word.
There is a linguist called Chomsky.
Chomsky's first operand is the word.
Chomsky's second operand is "1".
Chomsky is to compare.
If Chomsky says it's equal then I am to loop.

When this program starts:
I have an inputter called Dave.
I have a word called Input.
Dave is to read Input.
I have a truth machine called Hal.
Hal is to process Input.
```

The first paragraph defines a `truth machine` class with one member function, `process`, which takes a string (i.e. `word`).

The second paragraph defines `process`: write the string out, and then compare it against `"1"`. If it's equal, loop.

The third paragraph defines our main function: read a string in, instantiate a `truth machine`, and have the machine process the string.

Simple, really.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>5</s> <s>4</s> 3 bytes

<sub>[Crossed out 4 is still 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121108/73884)</sub>

```
wQc
```

[Try it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=wQc&i=0%0A1&a=1&m=2)

```
 w      Until popping results in a falsy value:
  Q       Peek and print with a newline.
   c      Copy the value atop the stack.
```

I'm loving this new language.

Thanks to @Weijun Zhou for reminding me of implicit input.

Comment: I am glad to find another user of Stax writing impressive answers. Maybe you should check out the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73911/stax) as well although there are not much to see at the moment.

Comment: You don't need the comma at the beginning. There is implicit input.

Comment: Also I suggest you use this link: https://staxlang.xyz/#c=wQc&i=0%0A1&a=1&m=2. It automatically runs your program.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Whoops, thanks!

Comment: [generator version(5 bytes)](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%7DgFQ&i=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Reflections](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/), 26 bytes

```
  _:#_: _<
/#_v     /
\: /
```

[Test it!](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##ICBfOiNfOiBfPAovI192ICAgICAvClw6IC//Mf8w/zD/MQ==)

Explanation:

The `_` at position (2|0) reads a line from input, `:` doubles the first character. Then, `#` redefines zero and `_` at (1|0) prints that character.
`:` doubles the first character again, `_` at (4|0) converts a digit to a number. `<` tests this number, if it's `0`, the IP is directed upwards (out of the program). Else it's directed downwards, then left by the `/`, and down again by the `v`, left by the `/`. The `:` doubles the character again. Then, the `\` reflects the IP upwards and the `/` right again, where `#` redefines zero and the `_` at (1|0) prints the character. The `v` then directs it down into the loop again.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) + `-np`, <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```ruby
p 1while~/1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DBsDwjMye1Tt9Q//9/g3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzCgA)

`~/1/` matches the last line of input to the regular expression `/1/`

Edit: replaced `;p 0` with the `-p` flag making the answer `-np` complete, thanks to @ValueInk

Comment: you don't have to count flags any longer; just note in the body which one you've used (as you already have done)

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks, is this the consensus opinion now?

Comment: Yeah, see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends).

Comment: @Giuseppe so should I call it `Ruby + -n`?

Comment: Use the `-p` flag instead to implicit print the zero ;p

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <strike>59</strike> <strike>51</strike> <strike>49</strike> 33 bytes

```
i=input()
while i:print 1
print 0
```

### Explanation:

```
input()             # take input from STDIN
while i:print 1     # print 1 if the argument is anything other than 0... input() evaluates the string and returns a value
print 0             # print 0 and exit if input() returns 0
```

EDIT: Saved 8 bytes thanks to @EsolangingFruit

EDIT 2: Coupla more bytes thanks to @HyperNeutrino

EDIT 3: Saved 16 bytes thanks to @HyperNeurtrino

Comment: You don't need to have `str(1)`, you can just do `print"1"`, etc.

Comment: remove the space between `print` and `'` (this is Esolanging Fruit's suggestion but you added an extra space so credit them instead for 8 bytes)

Comment: also, don't take arguments, use input. `k=input()>"0"` and then `while k:print 1` and then `print 0` (note that you don't even need to do `print"1"`, just do `print 1`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Thanks. Fixed the first thing... still looking at `input()` it's not doing what I expect it to.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino This is Python 2, so `input()` returns an evaluated value instead of a string. This means that `input()` already returns the number.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Right. Ok so then you can just do `k=input()` and then `while k:print 1` and then `print 0`

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 90 bytes

```rust
use std::io::*;fn main(){let
b=&mut[0];stdin().read(b);while{stdout().write(b);b==b"1"}{}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq7CoAgFADQva8Ih6iGsFXxS6JB8UaCD9ArDuK3m62HE3PC3nOCOaFmzATGdv742Unj161awEmJxWW86M1H@fWIIPWqNl5eY6EODRkHl2gQfldCKHKSVlvrnX4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 15 bytes

```
REeErEErReEEree
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#RE@N*)

#### Explanation:

```
REeErEErReEEree  # Full program
REeE             # Take input as number
    rEE          # Create label 0
       rReEE     # Output number -r (preserve)
            ree  # Goto label 0 if [input] != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 10 bytes

```
<1._
|@&
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/38ZQL56rxkGNy@D/f8P/uikA)

Answer (score 2):

## [VSL](https://github.com/vsl-lang/VSL), <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
fn main(){do{print(i)}while i>0}
```

This is probably familiar to anyone who knows any C-esque language but this takes input using a global variable `i`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyvO@Z@TWqKQaWv4Py1PITcxM09Dszolv7qgKDOvRCNTs7Y8IzMnVSHTzqD2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
p=QrwQpQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JzP3/v8A2sKg8sCDw/39DAA)

*-3 bytes thanks to the Q global variable*

Storing variables is a tad verbose in Clam...

### Explanation

```
p=QrwQpQ
p            Print..
 =             Assignment..
  Q              Global variable Q
   r             Read next line of STDIN (automatically parsed to int if possible)
    w        While..
     Q         Q is truthy
      pQ         Print Q
```

Resulting JS code:

```
console.log(Q = arguments[0]);
while(Q) {
    console.log(Q);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AlgiX](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/AlgiX) with `-x`, 3 bytes

```
[.]
```

### Explanation

AlgiX takes each character of input (converts it to charcode if it's not a digit) and runs the entire code for each value, initializing the accumulator to that value each run.

In this case, there's only 1 input, a `1` or a `0`, so the code runs once.

```
[.] - Implicit a = input
[   - If a == 0, skip to ]
 .  - Print value of a
  ] - If a != 0, jump back to [
    - Implicit output value of a
```

Normally, the implicit output after each run would output `a` as a character, however the `-x` flag overrides that and outputs its value instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [NuStack](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/nustack), 82 bytes

```
putchar(c:char):int;f(i:int):int{if(i>0)putchar('1');else while(1>0)putchar('0');}
```

Been working on this compiler for a month and a half. Still very much a WIP, but finally at a point where I can do some PPCG with it :D

Unlike all of my other languages, this isn't some toy, esoteric, interpreted language.
It's a serious language that compiles directly to assembly (nasm syntax).

I'll probably opt to get NuStack on TIO once it's notably more feature-complete than it currently is.

### Explanation:

Ungolfed version:

```
putchar(c: char): int;

f(i: int): int {
    if(i > 0)
        putchar('1');
    else 
        while(1 > 0)
            putchar('0');
}
```

The first line is a function prototype that allows you to call a function defined elsewhere (think C header files)

`putchar` in particular is currently the only function in libns, the language's standard library. It takes a single char, and outputs it to stdout. libns is currently available for 64bit linux, so it just makes a syscall using `sys_write()`, and 32bit "raw", ie not running on a kernel or operating system, where `putchar` will use the `int 0x10` interrupt to print the character in TTY mode

NuStack uses post-fix types, similar to TypeScript, and there is no type inference, so types must always be explicitly declared.

NuStack also doesn't have type casts yet, or do..while loops, so this is, as far as I know, the golfiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Verbosity v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Verbosity-v2), 290 bytes

```
IncludeTypePackage<OutputSystem>
IncludeTypePackage<InputSystem>
IncludeStructurePackage<Loops>
input=InputSystem:NewInput<DEFAULT>
outpu=OutputSystem:NewOutput<DEFAULT>
condi=InputSystem:ReadEvaluatedLineOfInput<input>
Loops:ConstructLoop<Do;condi>[OutputSystem:DisplayAsText<outpu;condi>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5RC4IwFIXf/TXRo82BpIEgGWlP0cPabjGybbjN8tcvNqOUejzc757v9NCdpeZmWDpXCNpaBs2gYEfojVwBVdYoa@pBG7jj6A9QiN97bTpLje0@UCml0jjink0mH/EWHiGiLN@kh7LBkfTCZKr10Ji/FJWC8VnTHgjLe9JaYoCVXEB1GZuDFEdhQryWQodxPqJMrkIRPs58GdeqJUOqG3gaFAa9uZNzixc)

First non-trivial Verbosity v2 answer! Although how it works *is* very trivial, as you can see from the ungolfed version:

```
IncludeTypePackage<OutputSystem>
IncludeTypePackage<InputSystem>
IncludeStructurePackage<Loops>

input  = InputSystem:NewInput<DEFAULT>
output = OutputSystem:NewOutput<DEFAULT>

condition = InputSystem:ReadEvaluatedLineOfInput<input>

Loops:ConstructLoop<Do; condition> [
	OutputSystem:DisplayAsText<output; condition>
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LDoIwEEXX9iv6C7pEJCGCCQkRI7gyLmoZTSO2hE5Rvh6hJIiP5c2cO@fWUJ2VFtgs2jaSvDA5ZE0JO8Zv7ApuYrA0mDYa4e6RP0Akf@8pVoajqUYoVqrUHiGihyld0UnL2cLDRjcIN/4hzjyirLTDpvaeG/IbJFzJXKBQ8uvnHlge1qwwDCGPhYTkMjjsgq5oFzlrJbXd2kc3UEs6PvTokcw@/IHQZcEaX2fwRHfYOC2QU9vOXw)

Simply enter a `do...while` loop, which prints the input at least once, then terminates if it's falsey (i.e. `0`).

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <del>5</del>  <del>4</del>  <del>3</del> 2 bytes

-1 for dropping block marker

```
q▲
```

### Explanation

```
Implicit input
Starts a block
q  Output TOS without a newline.
 ▲ Execute the code block while the TOS is true. Executes at least once.
Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/w0bRN//8bAgA)

Comment: I think you can drop the `Ä` since there's nothing before it now.

Answer (score 2):

### [tq](https://github.com/A-ee/tq), 3 bytes

```
?(?
```

### Explanation

```
?,   # Take an input
  (? # Extend the array while
     # the input is not false
```

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, 17 bytes

```
{while($0)print}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/ujwjMydVQ8VAs6AoM6@k1vD/fwMA)

Comment: Same effect, with 17 bytes, using a `for` statement instead of a `while`: `{for(;$0;)print}1`, or even `$0{for(;;)print}1`

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP v1.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), <strike>18</strike> 14 bytes

```
@A{1A:.}1M[!:]
```

-4 bytes with integer input.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=%40A%7B1A%3A.%7D1M%5B!%3A%5D&input=0)

Comment: Nice answer! You should specify it is MAWP 0.1 (0.0 is not allowed, by the way, because it is not a programming langauge at all).

Comment: OH, sorry about that, I just used the answer generator here: https://8dion8.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

## [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma), 8 bytes

```
[,].[.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=WyJbLF0uWy4sXSIsIjAiLDBd)

Dotcomma is a language I recently invented, designed to do things in an interesting way with as few instructions as possible. In order to accomplish this, there are two operators (predictably `.` and `,`) which can do entirely different things depending on context. This answer's explanation will be very introductory. To see some more complicated code, check out the examples in the page linked in the title.

This program is actually a pretty neat showcase of some of the more interesting features of dotcomma. You'll notice it's divides into two main parts, `[,]` and `[.,]`, separated by a `.`. These are called blocks. Every block and operator has a return value.

The way dotcomma manages to do so many different things with each operator is by changing what they do based on what precedes and follows them. Take the `,` in the first block. Because it is at the start of a block, its return value will be a value taken from input. Because it is at the end of a block, it will also output this value and use it as the block's return value. Surprisingly compact for a language with four valid characters!

As for the first `.`, because it is preceded by a block, it will take the block's return value and use it as its own. It is followed by another block, so it will do one two things: if its return value is `0`, the block will be skipped. Thus, only `0` will be outputted and the program will terminate.

However, if its return value is `1`, the block will be looped. Within the block are two operators: `.,`. The `.` will have a return value of `1`, as it follows the beginning of a block. The `,` will behave similarly to the first one, but instead of taking the number to be outputted from input, it will take it from the `.` (which will always be `1`). The loop will run forever because the `,` will always set the looped block's return value to `1`.

Hopefully this explanation isn't too confusing!

Comment: Why didn't I upvote this until now????? Every single Dotcomma answer needs an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

### [NDBall](https://esolangs.org/wiki/NDBall), 57 chars, 8 cells in 2 dimentions

```
(0)>0
(1)%
(2)Y[1,>0,>1]
(3)P
(4)E
(2,1)>1
(2,2)P
(2,3)<1
```

Visual representation of code (hand made by me)

[image]

Checked in [NDBallSim V1.0.1](https://github.com/aspwil/NDBallSim/releases/tag/v1.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
i[?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/M9r@/39DAA)

```
i[?  # full program
i    # if...
     # implicit input...
i    # is 1...
  ?  # output...
     # implicit output...
  ?  # without trailing newline...
 [   # forever
     # implicit end loop
     # implicit end if
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 35 bytes

```
n=input()
while 1:print(n);0/int(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer.

Comment: Also, golfing with suggested edits is usually not recommended, I'll leave a comment on xnor's answer for you.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thanks for the tip  I'll pay more attention next time

Comment: No problem, it happens a lot. Hopefully you'll get to 50 rep soon!

Answer (score 2):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 10 bytes

```
{,!"}
 >"^
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoieywhXCJ9XG4gPlwiXiIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIxIn0=)

There's a few ten-byters i've found, but I can't see any way to get lower. I was thinking of [this](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoieywhPFxufVwiXCJeIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IjEifQ==). but unfortunately that doesn't parse.

Answer (score 2):

## [v³](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V%C2%B3), 6 bytes

```
;@=.$#
```

Unwrapped:

```
  ;
@ = . $
  #
```

The IP starts at the top cell. `;` takes the input as a numeric value. The IP then falls to `=`, printing the value. It hits ground (`#`) and starts moving to the right. `.` is a no-op. `$` ignores the next command if the value is not zero. The IP wraps around to `@`, which terminates the program. The program repeats from `=` if it hasn't terminated.

Answer (score 2):

## [Built-out](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Built-out), 5 bytes

```
truth
```

Yay, built-ins! ...just kidding.

```
Before running: push input to stack 2

truth

t      - not last 't': swap stacks 1 and 2
 r     - convert character (1-9) at top of stack 1 to integer
  u    - toggle EOF loop if top item of stack 1 is falsy (0)
    h  - duplicate top of stack 1
       - implicit: pop item of stack 1 if not empty, then go to previous 't' if stack 1 is still not empty AND 'u' did not toggle it off, terminate otherwise
   t   - last 't': return here if stack 1 is not empty
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@BoTie/Built-out) (fork the project)

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Grok), 10 bytes

```
:}1j
z}zhq
```

Explanation:

```
:}      # If input is 0, goes down and to the left, outputs 0, 
z}  q     wraps to the right, and terminates.

:}1j    # If input is non-zero, goes to the right, pushes 1,
 }zh      prints 1, and loops indefinitely.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
Wq|c
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Wq%7Cc&i=0)

```
W    - loop over rest of program forever
 q   - print without popping, with no newline
  |c - exit if value at the top of stack is truthy without popping
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [2D Deadfish](https://github.com/Detective-Wasif/2D-deadfish), 7 bytes

```
(o^)>o<
```

It is a new 2D esolang based on Deadfish~ I made recently. Read more on it in the link in header.

**Explanation**

IP starts at the beginning with direction right. Statements inside parentheses is only executed if accumulator is 0. And input is set to the accumulator, or else 0.

So if you give input 0,

- Parentheses block will start
- `o` will output accumulator (which is 0)
- `^` will change direction to up
- It will eventually hit EOF token
- And terminate soon!

And for input 1,

- Skip the parentheses and jump to `>`
- `>` changes direction to right (It keeps moving right)
- `o` outputs accumulator (which is 1)
- `<` changes direction to left (back)
- `o` outputs 1 again
- `>` changes direction to right
- IP dances and repeats outputting 1

**How to run it?**

No online interpreter for now. but coming soon.

Until then clone the repo, and run `interpreter.py`. It will prompt you for the program first. When done typing program, hit CTRL+D (linux) or CTRL+Z (windows). And provide your input (if you don't want to give keep it blank) and hit enter. The program will start to run.

Answer (score 2):

### [Piet](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet), 12 codels

Codel size 16:

[image: 3x4 codel piet truth machine]

Instructions:

```
INN
DUP (start)
DUP
OUTN
PTR (back to start if 1; continue if 0)
POP
```

It has the following behavior for other values:

- if `n % 4 == 1`, print n forever
- else, print n once and terminate

if `n % 4 == 2`, there will be a stack underflow error, as the code path is as follows:

```
INN
DUP 
DUP
OUTN
PTR
SWITCH (empties the stack)
PTR (error)
POP (error)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AHHH](https://github.com/KyleM73/AHHH), 24 bytes

```
AHHHHhHHhhHHHHHHhhHHhhhh
```

AHHH is a somewhat more capable BF derivative in which every program consists of screaming.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRlrU9tG8LP1K9ZkMthghGVImjjAtE1ozJTSTpNMZpowjCydrBtkydXDhmb47XT3Tm@dBbZnMPLevm4ft7unqRm5j5YZwxmYruvq1mIBJyewc371YUc7PAT6@2UymcBfYTALzfmc@zO4NP1ZYs4YXPgxCxchw29CnN6P4fd7j8EfQThjfhQz7hP8FmH6vID9PJub3NOtYE6rq9VKJ4wSQrpEq5fcQiAbw8e/LmF5pA8JOGHmknv3wP1owUNmo2R4/@dX6OH/X/nsH3PhBnafMD@7DKI4TKw4CRk4QQgxQnihN6zMCEwvCmAahGGwQmZOGMyJHdH/xpiHAMYgDoDZPD5MInZoc@TJp0nMBoDfsPCYGTGwA383hoh5nrQZSjP9e7BZyJdmzJcMVkF4S2wvHLgPEkBeAnMAZiwZ8sBHpMTDLTGwgsBDucEALiBKFosgYmSVF9y3vMRmJ0tmxUF4VgCi2OaB7pYgFoI8Pq1CQnRiCcIDBDFzjiCbOdxncPXnzce/z88/X1x9/KRp8f2C4QLa0R6PpcwTtOAZzNn8nYZfsJDBIX/MyZP34nk85mhiEwlS6A3ugdMm68sph9K6hiIgZDM0NQuNm6XpJexdBTjKgNqUDFXgumYkl@AUHPQtolQwRioMbRlwG/5NeNwDgc0wHELoaz@0DnegJ372tQ7@7CzQgrHT2zknWPfQ3@m/Qyi7Q1qDHh@0zgvu@GS0iikLyu/@h8Bn@ndJ@oL5NsrIeAwR9pDuit0xq0cBS8EuAplCRGgVrXhsub3aglAQQwyz2cUniwJzOMYngoudNIwNp6cZTJ@ijfxenxjhR5oDuTMQW@zUSQ8OBJj089gSc@UUDAFZudxjvRR4BkPJUOgglHi@Dp0pBuetYCp@r1EhXRUb7O3VkfrEf5hxFFrt70s68cUwBp6kN15VGKSCH6Rds712CznCemS8fq49njlJ6KdebUiRRn7IHTjJHGjkDqzlEW0C0o/UooZAekuQjkEmjFrg/8if5e@Uu75IIvdmalq3IhSVOCUBFf5PoZPRitWH0nPu5nz/kzyAR9n@M/T2nRYBVFOmGs/FgnD/JoorlM2ddZQ7K8122HlpY6YPYK@ucr@V56TI4ONSBveUR12aX1D7dDq9ulSM5ebB2hHBWQEi2rCIcJWJmgRNYeUdqo/orgIs5CoMkhv5ldIgo6cNUv@0mmekMs@oYZ51vBs2U32abNuMuJ5aadKR2qRlmxZZ9jq3ad2x@2qlOutcShm2xoVFnvzUEDd6trjR88RNSkXwjeoMUXi/dIAX@Ws9mb0VX1cFqVNwxrB6m6HiyExrZ45AKu1@93erAtvOzkmpdrzNzdxUI62BTfIiKIxhC31aAhX0RelKa1fjYKK9YffsOCz8ZgyH13UzUE9hySRrLki6m4j/R/6nf4HTk8D@QaUDseCkgl2vCaojM9XKul7vJololeuvmn7YRFBQUCxmVAfGNdUy6XFl4ucWrwLLB5HW5G8R16qpFPyfF34KEcogx@aeZzsjeq11G3n8lCqfMWqJv/wMbkRgqVQYR20c9k5h9K5IVsmIerWHTsaqlAzHT7Daa8w5SuVK6VEtZKotyvOopWurdd@KVZx1l6pUajTTGM9oCTqozaWYeaNbvoCFGcXgsztMyGA@N30bVi7zwQuCW7oPoLFarNLMoTfkO@0TR70tLZEqo1w1WtQwVDndSW2w1xw1lcgNu2gqvG03l5Ln9XgN67ZBZB3LfLhRLCobknZZaF6KWfK1cDT5OAsDXcXrR7tm5T66jiCtSW5q2eOT3Kglo3GrDlMFZmVmUzBaNzC0Dy5uN0/v181hAEeBdJquUNrMMRMvJvxUrLiZSGdC@tLWxGU@Vso@6EHencxNnIHEzYEZzqwB0GG@t0c/ltmtRk8sYYEcQfVmg5T8EpkzNoaXkeCk0/Xgd1@MMcTi2/AailsPMEDee2id3y4uz/fAoYuVYMH8nsQ2rgewE07FxqVkh5x89eXysiH6ven7QQxEDVGQhBYDBzMevr2MrvVCAeO67JK6GuXu4jjtLWiki1ic1aMBDAdwjBRo2PR@yLTpPMvvhGQPEiR0XSiPT8knPYG6DpVSJ8vvUuQLQgcJ7eqpm3UGR9QZOFRhyRDluihTMSPtRnHoW/MFWoXuCXcGueqod3pBUmidtcGaTHSQk5Fc7VeqjII/5XWTv/pYLF0QUOLU22BokTHZRoaxkYzJVvsYbSZjq30cbSJjsp0/jjeTsdU@Xm0kYzt/vN5Mxlb7@GkDGZMt8@PNZjK22sfbjWRs5w9juJmQ7RLdSCtjO/ctU8MYPZP7drofPY/7luY/fib37XR/9Rzu1NgoS5CS5eviNjvnmtXSMyJWNEaf7v3YvAPxXmWcNdEwT3D8EHe6sOKxC7tUC3dFM5KpXar@uURaSAXKew5NVj@5s9JEVR@o1rQJ5TE1f6xe@9Q5peV@SOU@u@poXHTkCwXSaB3SqIR0hEidyupR7cIhVVQ0RI7lBRHL2g3166mSJ8jE@adLtj6/Y1YSUy8hGjFdL3eDshmT77FkM4ONMPe5bEOze3mx0HjHULQQa18tpBf6aZ/UHLjqr44ku7RNa6B3189nFB/dtW9narlUHt5qHbuWteRD6sfPrz5omnzLTkxFL02v2RH@KAxNRdKVtnbFs@s@CqLZ/j4cfDU9r3g9fxCId8aafiheMucMH4f/Aw)

#### Explanation

```
AHHH  Begin program
HhHH  Read int into current cell
hhHH  Write current cell's value as int
HHHH  Loop while current cell is not zero
hhHH    Write current cell's value as int
hhhh  End loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 33 bytes

```
n->ni+1,o->[1...n]0+i
i=0
o=0
n=0
```

The top line goes in a ticker, while the other lines are regular equations.

The input goes in variable `i`, while the output is shown in variable `o`.

Press the ticker (metronome icon) to start running the code.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xtjlvdm6va)

#### Explanation

`n->ni+1`: If `i=0`, it becomes `n->1`, so `n` will always stay at 1. If `i=1`, it becomes `n->n+1`, so `n` will infinitely increment by 1.

`o->[1...n]0+i`: `[1...n]0` creates a list of zeroes with length `n`. As shown with `n->ni+1`, if `i=0`, the length will always stay at 1; otherwise, it will keep increasing. `+i` simply converts the list of zeroes to a list of `i`'s. So in summary, if `i=0`, then the list stays at length 1 and is populated with 0's. If `i=1`, then the list length is always increasing and is populated with 1's.

The rest of the code: It is simply to define the variables used in the actions above.

Answer (score 2):

## tinylisp, 31 bytes

```
(d A(q((N)(i N(A(c 1(disp 1)))0
```

Defines a function `A` that takes the required input, as tinylisp has no concept of program input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRcFRo1BDw09TI1PBT8NRI1nBUCMFKKVgqKmpafBfw1HB4D8A)

Comment: You could if you so wanted replace all of the digits with `N` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### PostScript, 36 bytes

```
.runstdin 0 eq{0 =}{{1 =}loop}ifelse
```

Probably needs to be run through ghostscript to get the `.runstdin` operator.

Answer (score 2):

### Shell (posix), 26 bytes (code) + 1 (input) = 27 bytes

run:

```
$ ./<name> <1 or 0>
```

code:

```
[ $1 = 1 ]&&yes 1||echo 0
```

##### Explained:

`[ $1 = 1 ]` is a hacky way of evaluating if `argv[1]` is equal to `1`

in bash `&&` executes if the previous command finishes with exit code `0`

`yes 1` `yes` is a command that takes in a string and prints continually to `stdout`

in bash `||` executes if the previous command finishes with a non-zero exit code

`echo 0` self explainatory.

### Old versions

```
[ $1 -eq 1 ]&&yes 1||echo 0
```

```
[ $1 == 1 ]&&yes 1||echo 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

### [Leaf-Lang](https://gitlab.com/Breadleaf/leaf-lang), 43 Bytes

Note: Link to interpreter is liked above.

code:

```
input toNumber 1=while 1 print stop 0 print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org), 39 bytes

```
init log prompt()repeat while it log it
```

Full program

### [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org), 44 bytes

```
def f(n)repeat while n>0 log n end log n end
```

Function

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperscript.org@0.9.8"></script>
<script type="text/hyperscript">
def f(n)repeat while n>0 log n end log n
</script>


<label style="font-family:monospace">n: <input type="number"style="font-size:1.5rem;width:4.5ch"_="on change call f(my value)" /></label>
```

(Note: it will crash if you give it `1`)

AFAIK hyperscript can't take input from STDIN, so I'm using a function instead.

Ungolfed:

```ruby
def f(n)
  repeat while n > 0
    log n
  end
  log n
end
```

Comment: 39 byte “full program”: `init log prompt()repeat while it log it`

Answer (score 2):

### shell, 28 bytes

```sh
[ 0 -eq $1 ]&&echo 0||yes 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
p gets.to_i<1?0:loop{p 1};exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BotEngine](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BotEngine), <s>24</s> 3x7=21

```
v 0
>IS0>CP
  >eP
```

The digit 0 is a no-op, allowing me to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

## Loader, 30 bytes

run from `m.ldr` (or replace the `m` in the last line with the name of the file)

```
~B:set B =@IN
print B
B:load m
```

Theoretically infinite, in practice will result in `Error: Stack Overflow` in the reference implementation.

With comments:

```
~B:set B =@IN !!If B is zero (the default for uninitialized variables), set B to a number from the input
print B !!Exactly what it says on the tin
B:load m !!If B is nonzero, load a separate instance of this module on a copy of the current memory space
```

Answer (score 1):

## Math++, 11 bytes

```
?>a
a
2*a>$
```

Explanation:

```
1:Set a to a number from the input
2:Print a (the designator ">out" is implied if none is specified)
3:If a is 1, go to 2; if a is 0, exit
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @VoteToClose Done

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 9 bytes

```
{⎕←⍵:∇⍵}⎕
```

Explanation:

```
          ⎕  ⍝ read a number from the keyboard
{⎕←⍵:   }    ⍝ output it, and if it is true:
      ∇⍵     ⍝ call the function again with that input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [HSPAL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HSPAL), 60 bytes

```
110000
000000
420000
400000
420000
400000
120000
030000
040000
010000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stack](https://github.com/StackLanguge/stack-language), 67 bytes

```
{ '1' print a call } `a set '' input num 1 = a { '0' print } ifelse
```

Run by placing the stack folder into your python lib folder, and running `py -3 -m stack.cli truth.stack`

Answer (score 1):

### [3var](http://esolangs.org/wiki/3var), 6 bytes

```
">|[w]
```

Each 0 or 1 is followed by a newline. I've never actually used 3var's loop features before, so this is a first for me.

#### Explanation

```
"         Read input into R
 >        Copy R into A
  |[ ]    Do while A > B...
    w     Output R
```

Answer (score 1):

## Browser LiveScript, 54 bytes

```
switch prompt!
|'0'=>alert 0
|'1'=>while true
 alert 1
```

I believe I can use `prompt` and `alert` instead of `STDIN` and `STDOUT` with browser languages, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/pb), 21 bytes

```
^t[B]v<w[B!48]{>b[T]}
```

There is currently only one pb interpreter. It's called pbi and it's hot garbage. I wrote it, and I have 0 other experience writing that kind of program. The pb variables are global variables in pbi's source code, loops are implemented recursively (the tokenizer turns the entire code of the loop into a single token, then when it's reached that token is sent back into the tokenizer and is executed until the condition becomes false), the function to evaluate an expression is `def expression(e): return eval(e, globals())`... overall it manages to do basically nothing right and I'm probably going to rewrite it.

I bring this up because pbi in its current state only outputs anything when the program terminates, so a `1` input makes it look like it does nothing forever. Here are the reasons why I believe this answer is valid anyway:

- The canvas is being written to, which is how output works in pb. If the loop were to eventually terminate somehow, a lot of 1s would be outputted at once.
- There is a way to watch program execution in pbi. It's intended for debugging and it's about as horrible as the rest of the interpreter, but the flag `-d=` followed by a number will print the canvas and pause execution for that many milliseconds after each tick.

**How it works**

```
^        # Move the brush to Y=-1, where input lives
t[B]     # Save the value at (0, -1) to T
v<       # Go to (-1, 0)
w[B!48]{ # While the space under the brush doesn't have the value 48 ('0'):
           # (this loop is guaranteed to be entered at least once)
  >        # Increase the brush's X coordinate by 1
  b[T]     # Save the value in T to the brush's current coordinates
}        # If the input was '0', the space under the brush has the value 48 and the loop is
         # terminated. Otherwise, it repeats indefinitely.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <strike>83 77</strike> 76 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>int main(){int n;std::cin>>n;do{std::cout<<n;}while(n);}
```

Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>     // Needed for IO
int main()              // Necessary for any C++ program
{
    int n;              // Declare integer variable
    std::cin >> n;      // Retrieve input from STDIN
    do                  // Perform the following at least once
    {
        std::cout << n; // Output number, either 0 or 1
    } while(n);         // Continue doing so if number wasn't 0
}
```

Thanks to @feersum for letting me know that input can **only** be `0` or `1` I saved 6 bytes.
Thanks to @Alex A for saving another byte by removing a space

Comment: `n` is already 0 or 1 after you read it. `n=!!n` does nothing at all!

Comment: Oh so I needn't account for situations where STDIN contains numbers that aren't `0` or `1`?

Comment: 0 and 1 are the only possible inputs.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for letting me know! I will update my answer.

Comment: You can remove the space before `<iostream>`, saving 1 byte.

Comment: With certain compilers (e.g. gcc-5.1) you can omit the return type of `main` which would save you four bytes.

Comment: You can save a byte because you don't need to wrap the `std::cout<<n` statement into a block, `do std::cout<<n;while(n);` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

## [???](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%3F%3F%3F), 37 bytes

```
?!";.;.--,'",'";,-,,,,,'";...'";!-'"
```

This is a simple translation of [mbomb's Brainfuck solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62784/20469).

Answer (score 1):

## SWI-Prolog, 45 bytes

```
m(X):-put(X),(X=48,halt;m(X)).
:-get(X),m(X).
```

The `put` and `get` predicates work with character codes, so we need to test against 48 for the 0 case. If that succeeds, halt; if it fails, try `m(X)` recursively instead.

To run from Linux command-line, put the code in a file and execute `swipl -qs truth.pro`. (The `q` is optional; it suppresses extra output from the interpreter.) Or, [try it here](http://ideone.com/iDmNxW).

Comment: I guess you can remove the halt, since directives are only executed once (next() and close()). But the link somehow doesn't work, it gives an error.

Comment: On the other hand to be ISO Prolog compliant, you would need initialization/1 http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=initialization/1, since arbitrary directives are not allowed. The above would run in GNU Prolog.

Comment: @j4nbur53 The reason why I included `halt` is that with `swipl` on Ubuntu, not including it drops to a user prompt after the above code executes. I don't know what the exact policy on that is, but it seems like [extraneous output that can be avoided](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7371/16766), so I figured I'd better avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 31 bytes

```
@IF 0%1==01 echo 1&%0 1
@echo 0
```

On my machine, running `<script name> 1` twice from the command prompt caused CMD to crash. The first time it stopped after printing a lot of lines with `1`s on it. (Presumably because of CMD running out of memory.)

### Explanation

`@` – This tells CMD not to print the commands on this line. (Output will still be printed.)
`%1` – This will be substituted with the first argument given.
`%0` – This will be substituted with the script name.

The first line will output `1`s and then launch the script itself with an argument `1` if the script was called with the argument `1`. Otherwise, the condition evaluates to false and the script will proceed to the second line. It will then output `0` and exit.

Answer (score 1):

### [TML](https://github.com/WizardOfMenlo/TMLStdREPL), 14 bytes

```
d={1 or 0}/0000-1111/
```

e.g

```
d=1/0000-1111/
```

or

```
d=0/0000-1111/
```

Finally I was able to use my language for something :)
Since TML hasn't got an IO support (yet), the value must be hardcoded in the tape, but it should work as intended!
If the value is 0 it halts (goes to card 0), else it will print an infinite string of 1s

Otherwise I have a 2 cards solution using the default tape:

```
{0 or 1}/0000-1112/0112-1112/
```

Answer (score 1):

### ><>, 15 bytes

```
i6%   \
::n?!;>

i        Input character (by code point)
 6%      Modulo the top item on the stack by 6
      \  go to second layer

::       Duplicate the top item on the stack twice
  n      Print the top item of the stack as an integer
   ?!    If the top item on the stack is 0:
     ;    End program.
      >  Otherwise, move forward.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 6 bytes

```
riqJw!
```

Explanation:

```
ri -- read int
qJ -- shortcut for {J}, which is a shortcut for {^^}
      ^^ = duplicate
w! -- while loop
```

Mind you that the reference implementation of the interpreter buffers output so you'll run out of memory sooner or later before seeing any output in case you provide "1" on STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 9

```
~{.p.}do;
```

Equivalent to `q~{_p}h;` in [CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62734).

Answer (score 1):

## [Microscript II](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript), 3 bytes

```
N[p
```

Essentially a translation of the Microscript answer

Answer (score 1):

### [Aubergine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aubergine), <s>33</s> 24 bytes

```
=Ao-b1+bi=oA=bB-bA:Ab=ia
```

#### Aubergine in a nutshell:

Aubergine has four variables and four 2-argument instructions. The variables a and b can be indirected as A and B to point to locations in the program, which can be read and written just like data, making it inherently self-modifying. The other variables are o, which refers to input or output depending on whether it is the second or first argument of the assignment instruction, and i, which is the instruction pointer. The four instructions are assignment (=), addition (+), subtraction (-), and conditional jump (:). The only constant literal available is 1. All variables are initialized to zero.

#### Ungolfed:

```
=Ao                       Set the first character in the program to input character.
-b1                       Set b=-1.
+bi                       Add 6 to b, yielding 5, which is the location of the "1"
=oA                       Output the input value.
=bB                       Set b to the value of where b points, viz. "1"
-bA                       Subtract the input value from b, yield 0 if "1" and -1 if "0"
:Ab                       Conditionally jump to the location corresponding to the input 
                          value, either 48 or 49. Either is past the end of the program,
                          so execution will terminate. This will only happen if b is
                          nonzero, which happens when the input value was not "1".
=ia                       If we made it here, then the input was "1" and now a and b are
                          both zero, just like they were when the program began, so
                          we jump back to just after the input was read and repeat.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rotor, 4 bytes

```
{}|
```

Contains an unprintable, so here's a hexdump:

```
0000000: 7b1b 7d7c                                {.}|
```

Explanation:

```
        implicit -- evaluate and push input onto stack
{       beginning of block
  ^[    prints the top value of the stack (without popping it)
}|      execute block while top value is truthy
        implicit -- print stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [WTFZOMFG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/WTFZOMFG), 5 bytes

```
/\(\)
```

Explanation:

```
/        input a decimal number and store it in the cell
 \       print it
  ( )    while the cell is not 0
   \     print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/Nazek42/arcyou), 19 bytes

```
(?(#(l))(@ 1(p 1))0
```

Explanation:

```
(? (# (l)) ; If-statement on the input as int
  (@ 1     ; While 1:
    (p 1)) ; Print 1
  0        ; Else: Print 0
```

This is actually three bytes shorter than saving it in a variable and while looping it without the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <strike>27</strike> 29 bytes

```
for(x=prompt();alert(x),+x;);
```

The only interesting part is the +x which converts x to a number, otherwise the string '0' would return true.

Comment: @intrepidcoder Not to steal your thunder, but... :)

Comment: +1 Clever way to get rid of that trailing `;`

Comment: But it doesn't output `0`...

Comment: I completely didn't realize I wasn't following the prompt correctly..oops. You just almost beat me out, ha ha, but not quite. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 93 bytes

Terribly long.

```golang
package main
import ."fmt"
func main(){p:=Println
a:=""
Scanln(&a)
if a=="1"{for{p(a)}}
p(0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way 1.0.0](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 13 bytes

```
'?{0b~!~&{!}}
```

---

#### Explanation

```
'              # read input from command line
 ?{  ~ ~    }  # if-else statement
   0b          # push 0 to stack and compare to the previous TOS
      !        # output the TOS
        &{ }   # infinite loop
          !    # output the TOS
```

---

## [Milky Way (current version)](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 13 bytes

```
'?{0b_!_&{!}}
```

---

#### Usage

```
./mw <path-to-code> -i <input-integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 8 bytes

```
(?^(b!))
```

`==`

```
while input():
    print(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 95 bytes

```
class A{public static void main(String[]c){do System.out.print(c[0]);while(c[0].equals("1"));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [ROOP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ROOP),   12 bytes

```
I
wX


nw
hO
```

The w operator reads a number from the keyboard because it has an input object above (I). The input object moves to the right and the number created falls down. The X operator removes the input object, the n operator checks whether the number is zero. If the number is zero, the h operator prints the number and ends the program. If it is nonzero, the number moves to the right and the w operator infinitely prints the number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 45 chars

```
readline()[1]>48?while 1>0 show(1)end:show(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/atoms.md)

```
Ȯ¹¿
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=yK7CucK_&input=&args=MQ) (Keep in mind that online interpreters and infinite outputs aren't precisely compatible.)

#### How it works

```
  ¿  Convert the two previous atoms/chains into a while loop.
 ¹     Identity function. (condition)
Ȯ      Output/print without newline. (loop body)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 12 bytes

```
[[$.$][$.]#]
```

<kbd>[Try it here!](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda. Usage:

```
0[[$.$][$.]#]!
```

or

```
1[[$.$][$.]#]!
```

## Explanation

```
[            {start lambda}
 [$.$]       {output inputnum and check if it's truthy}
      [$.]   {only output inputnum if previous condition is true}
          #  {while-loop previous 2 lambdas}
           ] {end lambda}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Piet](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet), <del>16</del> 14 codels

codel size 10 for better visibility

[image]

Pseudocode:

```
INN → DUP → PTR → OUN → END
       ↑     ↓  
      PSH ← OUN
```

Old solution (16 codels)

[image: Truth Machine Piet version]

Pseudocode:

```
INN → DUP → DUP → PTR → OUN → END
             ↑     ↓
            DUP ← OUN
```

Much simpler than the oddly complicated Piet truth machine on esolangs.org.

Works on [PietDev](http://www.rapapaing.com/blog/?page_id=6) and with npiet 1.3a

Answer (score 1):

## [Gogh](https://github.com/zachgates7/Gogh/), <s>8 7</s> 6 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to @ZachGates

```
{ƤØ}?x
```

Run this in the command line like:

```
$ ./gogh nio '{ƤØ}?x:' <input>
```

#### Explanation

```
     Input is implicit
{    Push this code block
 Ƥ    Print TOS
 Ø    Loop forever
}
?    If STOS is falsy, remove the codeblock from the stack
x    run the code block if there is one, else do nothing
     If there is no codeblock, the program will implicitly output 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/node/Wierd), 225 bytes

Unlike other languages where the symbols in a program determine which instructions are executed, in Wierd, it is the bends in the chain of arbitrary symbols that determine which instructions are executed.

From the website:

> First, a Riddle:
>   Q:  What do you get when you put three marginally-sane programmers on a mailing list with the Befunge and BrainF*** programming languages?
>   A:  You get BeF***, and then they get Wierd.
>   ...
>  
>   Chris Pressey then jumped on it, created the angle-to-instruction mapping, and christened the entire mess "Wierd"--a cross between the words "weird" (which the language seemed to be) and "wired" (which would describe the appearance of programs written in the language).

Try it online at http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)

```
0           +  ++++ ++++++++++ ++++
1+  +++ +++  ++  +  +        ++  +
  ++ +  + +  +  +   +        +  +
     +  +  +   +    +          +
      ++++  +++     +     ++  +
        +            +  ++  ++
         +++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 1):

## Come Here, 29 bytes

```
0ASKaCOME FROMa-48 1TELLaNEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 7 x 2 = 14 bytes

```
~:#v_.@
   >:.
```

Comment: There's a lot of answers in this question so you might have missed it, but for comparison here are the links to two other Befunge answers :) [link1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/70733#70733), [link2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/63288#63288) (these are accessible via the leaderboard snippet)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fuzzy Octo Guacamole](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole), 8 bytes

```
^X({@}X)
```

`^` pushes input, `X` prints the top item on the stack. `(` starts an infinite loop.  `{@}` ends the program (`@`) only if the top item on the stack is falsy, like `0`.  The `X` prints the top item on the stack (again), and the `)` ends the loop.

So it repeats, printing and checking forever.

Comment: "languages created after this challenge are allowed to compete"

Answer (score 1):

## [Pylongolf2](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf2/), 11 bytes

```
1r1=?1>~<¿
```

Explanations:

```
1           push 1 to the stack
 r          pick a random number between 0 and 1
  0=        push 1 to the stack and compare them
    ?1>~<¿  if true, push 1 to the stack then print it forever.
            terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oration, 101 bytes

```
start a function t with x
inhale
to iterate, 1
literally, print x
if not x:break#
invoke t with input
```

Very long.  Starts a function called `t` with arguments `x`.

Inhale is a command used to keep the program running, you need oxygen to execute. :P

`to iterate,`  starts a `while $1` loop, so this becomes `while 1:`.

`literally, print x` just prints `x`, the function input.

`if not x:break#` is a simple if statement.  The `#` is there because the compiler appends a `:` to it, so that becomes `if not x:break#:`.  It happens to be golfier than the following good code with normal syntax.

```python
if not x
goodbye
```

`invoke t with input` calls the function.

Transpiles to:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def t(x):
    while 1:
        print x
        if not x:break#:
t(input("~> "))
```

Comment: Could you include the transpiled source?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ sure.  BTW, there might be a bug about the function call before 2 `backtracking`s.

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.3.3, 6 bytes

```
i:n?~!
```

[Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

This takes input `I`, duplicates, outputs as number, `?` skips if true. If false, `~` is met and the program ends. Otherwise, we skip `~` then skip `i` with `!`, and it repeats.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
​
I1r
```

Explanation:

```
print(top_of_stack) (if first run, print input())
if pop(stack):
    top_of_stack = 1
    goto_start()
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%0AI1r&input=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tellurium](http://m654z.github.io/Tellurium), 11 bytes

```
I?1|[i|^;]^
```

This program asks for input and converts it to an integer (`I`). After that, it checks if the input is 1. If it's 1, output 1 forever (`[i|^;`). If it's 0, output 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [eacal](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/eacal), 58 bytes

```
label l
put set n cast number arg number 0
if get n
goto l
```

`put` outputs `n`, which is cast to the first argument. Call like:

```
node eacal.js tm.eaa <input>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 36 bytes

```rkt
(do([n(read)])((= n 0)n)(println n))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JQuery, <s>63</s> 57 Bytes

```
if($("input").val()==1){while(1){alert(1)}}else{alert(0)}
```

[Try it!](https://jsfiddle.net/7awp7vr8/)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 28 bytes

```
{.say;.say while $_}(+slurp)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>22</strike> 21 bytes

Variable $a into the pipeline, prints once, then prints again if the input evaluates as true. Less elegant than TimmyD's but shorter.

```
$a|%{$_;while($_){$_}}
```

After looking at his though it could also be written as below, dropping it to 21 bytes

```
$a|%{do{$_}while($_)}
```

Comment: Sadly, taking input via a pre-defined variable isn't allowed here, since PowerShell can read from STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91892/58653), 6 bytes

Takes input from command line i.e. `./fish.py program.fish -v 1`

```
:?!;:n
```

Explanation:

```
:   ?  !; :n      ... (Since this is fish, it wraps around and repeats)
^   ^  ^  ^
|   |  |  |
|   |  |   Duplicates topmost value on stack and outputs it
|   |  | 
|   |   Skips the next instruction
|   |    
|    Checks if topmost value is 0 and if so, skips the next instruction, going straight to the ; which terminates the program
|
 Duplicates topmost value on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 33 bytes

Golfing suggestions welcome :)

```
x=input()
while x:print 1
print 0
```

Comment: This [doesn't work](http://ideone.com/hSGGLz).

Comment: @ABcDexter Ah you're right, I forgot the int. I actually initially wrote this in python2 where you don't need the int conversion and added the parentheses in later. Check it [now](http://ideone.com/4E3zyT).

Comment: [Somebody already beat you to the Python 2 solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62760/45941).

Comment: @Mego Theirs is [incorrect](http://ideone.com/gwGsxy).

Comment: @Mego Apparently, no. As the other code takes input again and again in the while condition.

Comment: [There's also this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62813/45941)

Comment: @Mego I didn't see that; it's excellent! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: That one is brilliant :D

Answer (score 1):

### [Ru](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/ru), <s>11</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/ru/blob/master/lib/codepage.rb)

```
»Ϟα;¿{»α}
```

<s>This look way too long</s>

Answer (score 1):

### [Straw](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), 17 bytes

```
(1>:&)(:&) <1='0>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Logicode](https://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode), 43 bytes

```
circ l(a)->1+l(a)
cond binp->out l(a)/out 0
```

Logicode can't output while in an infinite circuit loop, so this program will output ALL of the `1`'s after the infinite loop (when the program encounters a `1`).

If a truth machine that goes into an infinite loop when `1` is entered and has no output is acceptable, the code can be shorter by 2 bytes:

```
circ l(a)->1+l(a)
cond binp->out l(a)/out 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), 5 bytes

```
;:[:]
```

The braingasm instruction `;` and `:` are very similar to the brainfuck instructions `,` and `.`.

`;` gets some input from stdin, reads it as an integer, and stores the integer value in the current cell. `:` prints the value of the current formatted as an integer. Like in brainfuck, `[]` loops while the current cell is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

## reticular, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
[do?!]
```

[Try it online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=MSAgW2RvPyFdICBnOw&input=)

This is a function. `g` calls the function with the TOS as input. `do` outputs without popping, `?!` skips the next char if it's 1. Because of the way functions work, the *actual* constructed function is:

```
do?!;
```

This is made in a child instance of the program. Thus, if the TOS is 0, then it terminates (exits function).

---

Previous versions:

8 bytes:

```
indp?!;!
```

11 bytes:

```
in@@p;
p1 <
```

This goes right by `@@` if `0`, and up if `1` (wrapping around to `<`) and `p`rints `1` infinitely. It's in better style to do it this way, y'know, more readable. Because 2D languages are easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 30 <s>33</s> bytes

```
do{echo$o=$argv[1];}while($o);
```

Oops, didn't see the 7 other pages, one of which contains a better PHP entry.

#### Old 1

```
do{echo$argv[1];}while($argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <s>33</s> 32 Bytes

```
i=prompt();do{alert(i)}while(+i)
```

uses the `+i` syntax (thanks ETHproductions)

#### Old 1

```
i=prompt();do{alert(i)}while(i>0)
```

Comment: `0` is a falsy value in JavaScript, so you can shorten this by one byte with `i=prompt();do{alert(i)}while(+i)`

Comment: Nice one, wasn't aware of that short cut!

Answer (score 1):

## D - 87 bytes

```
void main(){import std.stdio,std.conv;int i=readln[0..$-1].to!int;do i.write;while(i);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 20 bytes

```php
<?L:echo$i;if($i)goto L;# 24 bytes
<?do echo$i;while($i);  # Martijn´s first version golfed 24->22 bytes
<?=$i;while($i)echo$i;  # Martijn´s second version golfed 24->22 bytes
<?while($i|!print$i);   # 21 bytes
<?while($i&print$i);    # 20 bytes
```

Requires PHP <4.2 or PHP<7 with `--d register_globals=0`.
Save to file, call in browser with `<scriptpath>?i=<value>`.

**explanation** for the last version:

`print$i` is evaluated in any case (no short circuit for bitwise operations).
`print` always returns true, which, when cast to int (by the bitwise `and`) evaluates to 1.
For `$i=0`, `0&1` is `0`, hence false and the loop exits.
for `$i=1`, `1&1` is `1` and the loop continues.

shortest version(s) for **current PHP**, 29 bytes:

```
while(($i=$argv[1])&print$i);
while((print$i=$argv[1])&$i);
for($i=$argv[1];$i&print$i;);
```

Run with `php -r '<code>' <value>`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyramid](https://github.com/Qwerp-Derp/Pyramid), 14 bytes

`+1` byte to specify starting on stack `1` (originally 13 bytes).

```
1<
b
---
?<
u
```

Pyramid is my new-old language, which is based off Stackylogic. It has a bunch of extra commands that will (hopefully) make it TC, which include moving up and down multiple "stacks".

Explanation:

```
1<   1: Move down the stack, and push 0 to the output stack
b    Break: outputs the stack, and resets it - also runs the stack again
---
?<   Input: 1, 0: If it's 0, move up, push 0 to the output stack, 
     terminate the program and print the stack
u    If the input is 1, move up to stack 0
```

Comment: The leaderboard snippet is reading your header as saying that this is 1 byte. You should probably move the part in parentheses to the second line (and, if I understand it right, change the header to say 15 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), 9 bytes

```
id?v
|o<o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#@5@ZYl/GVZNvk///vwEA)

I'm aware that there already is a Haystack answer, but that answer uses the older version of Haystack, this answer uses Haystack 2016 (and it's much shorter)

#### Explanation

```
id           Take input and duplicate it
  ?          If input is truthy (1) continue, otherwise (0) go down
```

If input is truthy...

```
?v           Go down
 o           Output number
             Since this is a 2D language, the IP wraps around and does this infinitely
             Also since Haystack (new) doesn't pop the top of stack after outputting
              1 can be printed forever without needing to duplicate it
```

Otherwise...

```
  ?
  <          Go left
 o           Output number
|            Exit program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 3 bytes

```
#$#
```

Extremely simple:

```
#    \ Print input
 $   \ While input != 0:
  #  \   Print input
```

An input of 0 will print, skip over the while loop, and terminate, whilst any other number is considered truthy and will be printed infinitely.

Comment: ...what's with the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

### Evil, 74 bytes

```
fjzaeeeaeeawbmxruuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuusbaeeeaeew
```

A program that will request for a character of input. Every lowercase letter corresponds to a different instruction. Here's an analysis.

`f`: goes **F**orward in the program and searches for the closest marking character, or `m`. This skips all of the code that will continuously output `1` to *stdout*.

`jzaeeeaeeawb`: Continuously output `1` to *stdout*. The character `b` searches **B**ackwards for the marking character. However, at this point the marking mode is set to 'alternate', so instead of searching for `m`, it's searching `j`, which is at the beggining. The random amount of `e`s with `a` and `z` set the counter, or accumulator, to the ASCII representation of `1`. `w` would do what you might think: **W**rite the value of the accumulator to *stdout*.

`mxr`: This is executed right after `f`. The marking character has now been found, and we continue with `x`, which switches the marking mode from 'standard' (`m`) to 'alternate' (`j`). Then, `r` **R**eads *stdin* for a character and sets the accumulator to the ASCII representation of the input, which would be either 48 for `0` or 49 for `1`.

`uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuusb`: Each `u` decrements the accumulator. The whole operation brings the accumulator down from 48 to 0 or 49 to 1. This is crucial for the following command; the letter `s` will **S**kip the next command only if the value of the accumulator is 0. That next command searches backwards for `j`, which goes all the way back to outputting `1` to *stdout*. Note that I could probably shorten the amount of bytes here by replacing some `u`s with `e`s, which [weave](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil#Weaving) the accumulator.

`aeeeaeew`: Now, if the accumulator had hit 0, this snippet puts the accumulator back to 48, or `0`, and `w` **W**rites the accumulator value to *stdout*.

Original interpreter in Java: [http://web.archive.org/web/20070906133127/http://www1.pacific.edu/~twrensch/evil/evil.java](http://web.archive.org/web/20070906133127/http://www1.pacific.edu/%7Etwrensch/evil/evil.java)

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 10 bytes

```
:{?a~a|\_X
```

Explanation:

```
:    Reads a number from the command line and names it 'a'
{    DO - infinite loop
?a   Print 'a'
~a   IF 'a': 0 is seen as false, 1 as true
|    THEN: Empty THEN block, we want to act on FALSE
\_X  ELSE exit the program.
     _X accepts one implicit parameter, and prints that parameter on exit.
     Since no parameter is given, nothing gets printed.
[IF and DO are implicitly closed by QBIC]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Threead](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Threead), 5 bytes (Noncompeting)

```
I[o]o
```

`read`, `while not 0 output`, `output`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#@@8ZnR@b//@/IQA)

Comment: Huh, I hadn't even thought about having the single output be *after* the infinite output, in any language...

Comment: @ETHproductions it doesn't make a difference, actually. `Io[o]` works too.

Comment: Also this is a catalogue so it is competing (kinda)

Answer (score 1):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 8 bytes

```
i.o.&#@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@5@pl6@npuyg/P@/AQA)

#### Explanation

```
i     Read a byte X from STDIN (gives 48 for input 0, 49 for input 1).
.o    Duplicate X and print that byte back to STDOUT.
.     Duplicate X again.
&#    Skip X commands. Since the program contains 8 commands, if X = 48, 
      this doesn't really do anything. The IP will just loop through the 
      code six times while skipping all commands. But if X = 49, it skips
      one more command, so the next command is skipped.
@     Terminate the program (only gets executed for input 0).
#     Skip the i at the beginning of the next iteration.
```

This code loops indefinitely, unless the `@` terminates it on the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 25 bytes

Straightforward, but nevertheless annotated:

```
5  # read into cell 0
0
10 # if cell 0 is equal to 0 (from cell 1), go to cell 11 (*) else 7 (&)
0
1
11
7
4  # print what's in cell 4 (a zero) &
4
6  # jump to cell 7 (&)
7
4  # print implicit 0 *
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/braingolf), 5 bytes

```
[!_];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Rxrc9s28rP0K2DXCUXrEdlp71o7ds5J005mmjRzmbkvilpBFGXTlkiWDyUZV/fXc7uLN0nZki@9meuHKgQWi8W@ASx8zVc8D7IoLfpxMgu/BEmcFyzNkiDMc3bGsvCPMsrCjiebPP@0LWDmTvecemTX7zmfh9Dr7XkK@vcsXIVZTq3/Nq15tAjjAhsPTONlFoazz9j42DQuk1k0jwAFtI9ogp5G2lOIemrwWI@TdL@O3xdZFF/iaO/DB6/HvH1vjBQvOCz0xc9vklnObtstGpaVQZFkHR8bWsVVlA9WfFEi8SMY01q32y0@m3WWAMCiOevsEcwVz6HJZ2bAIC3zK2g7Zet2KwvzsECcrIoRe8Vg6MzCosxilhe8CAc0hkh7bqON4mBRzkIaccLmfJGHiGRtlvO@4MFNdT1RHBURX/wLcTSsze5mf/5p1kqrAKi8h2RlhRiLCy8@p2Eypz6fnZ2ByHJisydAWouwYMUyBeQIcopN@A/FyFZrnmSsg1ARtA1P4ecZDhiANC@LK/judiUqGigYigDBFc9egsZeFJ3I9wkXcLG1ZiEwgzXSth@Xy2mY7ftM0YC/RIcetHeRZfzzIMrpVwxGiWbJR/Yqy4CJk5c89goG8gelvUWAtceKBDkT3Owxwb1lCbo3DZngRo9xxNZjsFhBQ49Ny4JdJgU7uLXpXE/QigRvJasdEREPQKQBLzqmw9dLcIAthZFDaA4l1CQVU/RYkJSxFCqKApSuXBRaRk0iohG2dLB/Bf2E0VXW/Cqao96fOIYBswupidmEYFfUhHKUViA6ieJWGoY3/xOKR9HYIXZk0S30st@Jukf@eCf6263LaBVKdVSEi8nPpLWDjxNeRDk2Qkez10xQ8KTgN2GHlgZIjnbDS3DCUVfBsJlgpB46ncLDglWoeWvsOTUMQEzIJcnfugyxUzK7ppG0RuDcimeCRJgMVjgLp@WldHs9@fk6noH/P2FDaMiTMgvCE1ZC2zyKwxm0RanoCz9FhRlKNpufgNrghwRZ8igm9yk@F0mSyk8CA1OagZ8EtyobkDMnLA4/yijSk67@DbWrqSIZgOzJxbfnIV15wNNwZnr5bMVjXAU4b/xOAbj4NX5F9Iu29algTZLmgjEY2E4YmNrZufbQe0J8anpfxhcUUTXEnMlI4shdEuZLV8a64ONhGu1xHChUBiAN5QYke98gNZFDTsS67IidK5UTopJqY9NG1skXrAJoe33EREq6It50Jm/DTwVDCBbl4FftgSOCHq9Zh1z22p/4hgNCC0byIx0PlKFaMFHa7apl7TtMvoeLNf7fMknv/ovwMopjZKrg7T7kCS604icmCCZGbRbMvpEL@Tg1k8QWJMsUGBue7AvXK7sVF0SoEjxt1QjRq7qTazYu34GWaDzParW5JhUHvRpx@R@u8qBCkFe4yASaHrtGn9fTbugIR3@8gkRQqNk1eP0GLWOPH7OaalyPB0teBFedJ6Nh/4fxE18GCT1j96xpEC3lmjSDvL4AkaZr80wpEWZZOFJph8KvaDtnQys8qZWlHHz2a5CUAhecRQRvKZ2AfOUtfyu6q@nKW0gyONpSNJPJxx4mLgrV2pvooCWNLjdWV5UxxRvjV42fllEng6FCYwbzLFm@lOY64Gm6@NyJy8Wix1QS0lLal/nKsn53LKvmAxqp0XEKQA0bj3w5dDISFj/@EE@0ccgu6hkNx@uJIUeaPZFzVvOmG2MhyUz6oZH2PUQwaBbEtbNzb@R1VZy8TqK44/U8v@uNPV99fog9fz2e@CaPvQOtxQfCSSv0bQs63dZPiS4rwlidhKmrMWVl/GsaZhy3E8fQ1TITKHfivY0WfBYFLF2UkK5g5oKmfzzUWfLA8@91JMdDsRaag9cmmbxJYmuSWVJOFzjLwS1fDyb3o@dghdyaQe4Szo3x6ZyScu4snJVB2OlwyNwJDhFMHTc6eSdXKnYFQqj7ALbvrwHNwa3AuDZs2IJOMUaJ1Udh9B8kjGUU29LoH@0kjf7RdtKQs@TltMh4UCiJMHQGLCrycDHfTjr9HaVDaW3Hb5JTfzs59b@2nA4fJidAE4GzNKI6Gg53Mx0csKW49GT5HyXPdjOgw//WgA63E8zh1xbMkwcJZhatolloxPLdTjL5bjuBqEnoV1vP9PNOtvPka9nOG15cDeawAcoI69TfRlxPvra4fnuQuMJPaRLTkaBtRw8xpa2tyUyZ8Sh/qPQOD/8S8R0ebim/3762/B49zA8ms9LJH452F92WTlDNRP9IHiq3R3@J2B5tKbVHX1tq59smjztk6YbzK70CRWhWsGTuUHxXsjsoY3GsaKfrz74ayc7B5Z2Uh/FsJ7rVOZ4metBANO0v8ILBHMQ9gMs/lukiCnhhEZzE21BqH38Qjb3atmyE2jq@h5pjvTXjdP6u9414uTB1m3zXC/yCt0/FFY/ZMRhhuMw16T0WXcYJpSqJ9CXKG5jTo7XFhvcfYfOpjZqDvA5up@v7GSCWqHkw1Dy4a9CQbOdoK9gjgj3eCvaYYJ9uBfuUYL/dCvZbgv1uK9jvCPZvW8H@jWD/vhXs3wn2@61gvyfYH7aC/YFgFzXdXYTxfZZvjrGrXlceMCiT74EyQdO6V3W3dxEGA7RazRqD49G9ueglbNLzMOUAHyWxiZK7xUgrQtLZTD1y3eMixOHGSoMTg4k6dLirQZGI0yCIczl4I1iCpMqYJzYrH7Vm0Jaw0cGtwIGHIQJcXieIZpp0hpPqk7GZugNs2gKq6y8IpU6M@7GmG7TQe7RDuWMQ1rIsiP@4WPFJJ6DBjW8F@By8MFo7kkeUpzijuC@gi4VO6td0pkKDWoE9p9ahfLMOiRO3ryRbLTLwwGgBQmB41E4pSw7NnZWvd49KZnanlJEjhex/RD4lYej/z@wUi/6JzckSiDhkq4p@/hzGSBEELQEkz1Ax0YJvyBLD4mMIHmUoQ8uqtn6Ea1r3v2raBzrxXiqgrR46ATA1FPfd60UQVz9RfYYY8RzoO3E1yvg4jNAKQZ21eKuqCBsrPbQBbDej787Mmbh1SyRnphxIoXRSlpdZSKzG1QtT5GotB7f06wZuOk/HZmUKqxpPt@cZTPpask2j72rOAAv7R8DDI53UaPhneGhfH22zmfXF9YQz7rwR1EE1PHUymagIyMsrHw9cUcB1xqgexZugxhtdaLPhWFvfYclvoRzmHBynOdOjleh91114FwuQKkwDGRzCqMAZJ/0k9RxT0VUcJt8Os0txQSZWq@aVgcLgkza3iw93tJzCU6Dvr1J9D@as9ll9rZWGfn9T0NUg5qZMar8ttArsaeUqQPFU8YUvFkyaaYUhnmGIxtbMFIswwxvNyFokQq/agd2yuJrrRGyvSQWeM1WHgrfk9wTl0w0@R3tAjdjyP@h5ZAnGZv4pE1JXIsvtb3SsDrkdtDXEaicH9OtcD1Wqs92W7ehO/9PkNnZwN87EakjDBu/N/xlbuv@FN92WJ//c7fZsg/USqndN15r5vccPxFc7@KvDI9ljckwrSngvk2XKRQ2eHTxGslZNZtQKGnKTGhygVWDOwVWHqthe/VECHlmLBKA@GjtGxmHTfmnjedR2x1HEvvSvTBCB3mX4E8f6yJxS9NYOG4hylxOn@7K7beKWrRRNVW6Cw/XiSWnS0KfMkr5G0diHURHWcsWwCZPOX1FqBSqEdKscqgSKZTl6P3JLOO7gj1KbX5IkFaeBkAVyrI6M1kYTZcEHVmS9lKURw@2KPuyiCra5lINKMkQd60iVsLb0dCKntUtMJexYw2KjIY@qOfSnTA2s8hx5HoFrPlMtLVr9CYt68juMZyeiaES2rAUal2d4DjmHWRTXEH6tNiKS87qSTWTg@KkAppCi3Yh/r3USZgpbSJrjXZR9HmV5sVmZqQ6QqtgqNVy0GKoqCWUZF2GSS0H2SszV80TR/OxMF9BUMIrKJ@cs3OKHqkZtyLUIAbgyK8OUEqtgGVWxmlhspylUBIRAA5K0zeHnrr2At3upig35ohP1LPaLU1jwCeNtjoTVVhTj7p7DucePqfFcpkna54a7krL9gbAihtdJmdab8OiYTV3iXu1IHFFDcf7CyiJO690vGpIM4zslyKZEw0UzbBh7obZLCk5VPOriN0PPRQMvFZqGYGAGvtg88EXTQE3ihVLYPUXki0phplUDqIPPtQg@1yr4XOjoc21K980co@uxhR@@GnCvLSXRVYFa@Cf1usAR1uQa5TMVuoN5tABHgn76nAUDsm0UQeSbAjw8EHJvIsxmVGVJP5FnxeGeM3IgMxV3c6aVkX3kuajVZflNJG4hiIZgwUuFy3YLhDMUx0VrKn4@bbfnZRwQNjv7IRcJmQ8eCOPNZYw/abL4zMVVypalfKJ@T7EppoNJ1waRRsqzcSY0yL0NWwPpSvQWBJmKGxUcR6qmoyZRuyuqI1@skjK30XCsMYpFq6cNa5dfFb@gNUPzCFG8SyCTBa7D72nbTjQQ3E40ts0z7kkzrMzhuYexS36E9scrT5egSiJkNK5lH396VpJnSKbkQ3/K5MPKPcSC7YJUOw1YN0514qFoLLacmXgrOWkjRCQiicDnD6Kilc5fZQKh8xwcC1atULgKCNsL1eHW9IvUSKyj11YvMU6MlDuQ0GO2VHMLlP/gN7220aeP2m6JtlwnoIC7yzrC4oklNQInPQYKLPhFozTsesKwxN8nHBM6JAaKcxsqnon0pk4HJUCWo1Gk7FltYnbtX2CbdXC7iVSA9ciLIU0hbv0UecQIOuur@bWaf2pCa3pObC@2dgxS15tnYG@fioyLVxtoXeC8MkD2SRaC08xW@Ty98bA8swgoWdVziwJkKjGX7/7A783CLBt8zKICtnRyEmDD6McXP4/PmWdJx2PwnwdrT0N9xG09LgGttoiWAsUjyWz9IQbBkPfRazXFzWop1YxZ16Fb727oFaNvLdRaRlIWchmiZNrmrL0zF9tWOSm3g/p0Uzxv2kry@jaSEOLrKEJGm8cKInrmaAVum0Z7p90xHhinPJZ@dy561UMu7W8PkSLYXxoyYvYIt62RcIrGrcXu7U7Mnshg35K4he1HulBaRjdRMu7A0CWtXh91VBYkb/ysSzkiEN/kqMhl3xJKhhpXheu0@2Vaho@KWoE8JhDvEKXcMFAvRJFBKxIx6gYs57TNmMWtZ8wORuS@UWi0zycm3ZCTfsSOyZtDHzEodanVzU5TBeamDnNDMNTc7WrkkXqg4byXa1h8bRsWiFmHEmNkBFd5Y@eIhtO5GElDvoH5Z0lvbQaDwb7lbPffi8didtvkQ@y@HkL77qGPIjW3IV@LJ7Py7IayqRNWKf8XwnBcPHlbKS/p4fBh2h3Zg3LCY3N2Zrumyk3R63eGiihdQyaD3wE9fwrsR1RD330K5eIkgREr8SFHJyBA@0KKVg1B6t6nCfSmwTjBCK9Shpjt6O9NT8IMd6zHZe1WeyMTzCz2gwbz6Oeuig/z/sbyzPLdtjrZWPC7DjbEntuqe3AON3CouBUBpnkHt4hLPcARMNhCWx1jAWpb8Q5/8BaNmDGLcj5dhOL0di3fB3Y8fEJiaferT2FQkkWoE5C9fb/BVKR8cb7qGybJ843nPTbH9XMxTO6rT@/Nq/XAt5ls3q8FZuGI07z5rw9VLL2YUZm0giQttxVal9IFlTo@ifnE6K65u5Cn35YMNj9Xw00GMa@ndVm9sG4I@ncolztC8t9n9vPD6uZGzivcOh1JJWk@CsbSCqClkqgmKUW@mvgvskvIG@B/OiqTYqu9z1MZnqM4LfHNmArQVuIAg7EkRONo5XRZjXcGl4O8nAohd8CHHuu3dRyY6/VX3knbnFGSPVvstfckckBuBhgSdSGQO9@xvFysv5Uzo6sP5l7H4rGc49PBWKuYleHaJAKnOe5BxJyKXSLYcfVuz8CvhdhlJGi6yHtmScJvLqMwNwkUVrSg7AvQqpw0aVZiB8uTbyB/w0eQbNw90O8greMEYoOo5WKePjrg4p5E5Sl4s8KdAi3ecM07MnR2u9bFTC0HaJ7@/tm5G@t2pcB@fk5RCR8Nfhnt/T4@/TI5bes2GbKMckBe5r457dMxt7G6MueXodA34nCjAqJ89tovkywLg0IMAcU6uFV7AmDFaoSPmp/Ncd/Al@E5GyUpbXHHMCVkPDmbZhwoShZz0ORZSPc8nPZsUWyNa0Tbh1QSB9lYN6CdRUjj4rN46FVc4UTLJWx2@wuYrP2rGA7U91etVZhNE/yjLeSLc/xLGvKIhgnrh40OCIXh2RkgivAqAPZteCEATi8HHPk38uU@7HTwDTVsvHWcA7dzxb6RtQsD9qMwyBz3xU8xqsQJ/XkbfGYzI/tVy8aoStfOIHG0B5sdxhqfUibhyNYcgthSvRMPJDtP9RbN4fvxWPypkv5835hmMynf@sydUN28LMK3IFN0ijbmpyJ1VDo7x9jDZz8B9PvPcdBRw3rMK4t5/3txOGmig0ODyNW/9X03YDevJJIr0VM3kLXbPJv4b6bQMc8N43dOI2KFDsMSVb1I3f1jMEm5mJFSITelZuxN5J@u0DPfPzHMa@e/2quctsVeRnwB4Jcv/dWXo/8A)

#### Explanation

```
[!_];   Implicit input
[..]    Do-while, run once and loop while top of stack is >0
 !_     Print top of stack without popping
    ;   Prevent implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (Node), 40 bytes

```
for(;console.log(v=process.argv[2])|v;);
```

In Javascript for the browser this can be 29 bytes

```
v=prompt();for(;alert(v)|v;);
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 6 bytes

```
$.(]%<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0VPI1bV5v9/g/8A)

This formats into the triangle:

```
  $
 . (
] % <
```

The commands that are executed (without control flow) are `$(%]`. Pretty simple.

- `$` read input as integer
- `(` open loop
- `%` print as integer
- `]` jump back to loop if top of stack is truthy

Answer (score 1):

## [ILL](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/ILL), 19 bytes

```
/RnN~
>1nR\
\   /
```

ILL (inverse linear law) is new right now, so this represents virtually all the instructions/groups of instructions it has at the time of posting this. The main idea though, is that the program is run by light, which reflects off of mirrors and decrease in intensity as it moves on (obeying the inverse linear law, because its 2d). Data is primarily stored in the intensity of the light, which can sort of be used as a control structure, since light with an intensity < .5 dims and does not move on to the next tick. This means that different intensities of light move different lengths. This program utilizes the dimming behavior to either halt after printing 0, or prints 1 and continues. Basically, it takes a numerical input (side note: instructions that set intensity actually do so after the current tick has run, and they also persist the light over to the next instruction, no matter what intensity it has), prints it, and then re-intensifies and enters a loop. However, the light is only re-intensified if it reaches the re-intensify instruction, which light with an intensity of 0 will not. More detailed explanation (also a valid ILL program):

```
/RnN~
>1nR\
\   /
#END OF FILE#
Truth machine.

~ : emits light horizontally at the start of a program.
N : takes numerical input, set light intensity to the input.
n : produces numerical output. If the light has an intensity of 0 here, it will dim after n outputs and not move on.
R : re-intensify, if the light made it here, it can now continue into the loop.
> : double/splitting mirror, allows the light from the above / mirror to enter the loop and move right.
1 : set intensity to 1.
n : numerical output.
R : re-intensify.

the remaining \, /, and \ reflect the light back to > where it can start the loop again
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```cs
class p{static void Main(string[]I){do{Console.Write(I[0]);}while(I[0]=="1");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv1fWpyZl64QXFlckppr/T85J7G4WKGgurgksSQzWaEsPzNFwTcxM0@juKQIqC461lOzOiW/2jk/rzg/J1UvvCizJFXDM9ogVtO6tjwjMwfCsbVVMlQCitT@///fEAA)

I've seen some disagreement about whether arguments count as STDIN. "No" seemed more popular, but if it were acceptable then this would save 15 bytes over the previous C# answer.

Saved 1 byte by removing an unnecessary space

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 6 bytes

According to the spec, this should work:

```
$(%7)7
$      - Get user input as number (either 1 or 0, according to the rules)
 (  )7 - do ... while input value is nonzero
  %7   - Output the input as a number
```

However, TIO seems to continue the loop even if the input is 0. The [Lua interpreter](https://github.com/Cubically/cubically-lua) handles it correctly, though.

Comment: `$:7(%7)6` works on TIO for now. It should behave identically (instead of looping based on the value in 7, it sets 6 to that value and loops on that) but it doesn't, meaning there's a bug in the interpreter.

Comment: Works offline and Dennis should be pulling. Good job, can't believe I didn't notice this! I always thought a truth machine had to print 1.

Comment: @MDXF It does print 1. The rules state that the input will either be a 1 or a 0 :P To make it print 1 always, just do `:1/1%6` instead of `%7`

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 58 bytes

**Code**

```
: f getc '0 - dup 0 1 between if repeat dup . while then ;
```

**Explanation**

`: f`                - Start of word definition

`getc`               - Get input from STDIN

`'0 -`               - Subtract 0's ASCII code to determine numeric input

`dup`                - Duplicate result to be used to run loop

`0 1 between if`     - Check if input is either 0 or 1

`repeat dup . while` - Print either 0 once or 1 ad infinitum

`then ;`             - Exit word

If input is not either 0 or 1, exit with no output. At the end of the program the stack is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 20 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and output `1`, infinitely if `[A1]` else `0`

```vb
While[A1]:?1:Wend:?0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Whitespace, 40 bytes

Note that the only valid characters are space, tab, and linefeed, so they are represented here with S, T, and L, respectively. Comments are also given.

I used [this interpreter](https://whitespace.kauaveel.ee/) to write and test this program (warning: crashes browser window upon input of 1).

```
SS L   # push 0
SLS    # duplicate
TLTT   # readi
TTT    # retrieve
LSS L  #label "" (blank label name, why not?)
SLS    # duplicate
SLS    # duplicate
TLST   # printi
SS STL # push 1
TSST   # subtract
LTS L  # jz label "" (jump to blank label if input-1=0)
```

Three consecutive linefeeds (`LLL`) are usually required to end program execution at a point, but that interpreter doesn't seem to mind if you leave them out. If they have to be added in, the score would instead be **43 bytes**.

Comment: The interpreter defines the language, so the missing LLL should be completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//github.com/aaronryank/simplestack), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
$(%)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/19FQ1Xz/38DAA) Prints `00`, which is equal to `0` Pretty simple:

```
$(%)
$      « integer input               »;
 (.)   « do..while top of stack true »;
  %    «  print top of stack         »;
       « implicit integer output     »;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

Like [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137877/63757), but in Pyth

```
WQ1)0
```

Explanation:

```
WQ1)      While Q, print 1. 1 = true, 0 = false; end While
0         Print 0
```

If input is 1, `0` is never reached, if input is 0, `1` is never reached.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzzQUNPg/39DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 28 bytes

```
3.61448701501132011483250194
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M/n/31jPzNDExMLcwNDUwNDQ2AhImFgYGwE5lib//xsCAA)

Explanation:

```
3.            Start Program
6 14 48       Set the value of memory cell 14 to 48 (the ASCII code of '0')
7 01          Read in one byte to memory cell 01
5 01          Print byte from memory cell 01
1 32 01 14    Set the value of memory cell 32 to cell 01 - cell 14
8 32          Start loop: if cell 32=0, skip to the end
5 01          Print byte from memory cell 01
9             End loop
4             End program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
¶?∞;I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9A2@0cd86w9////bwgA)

#### Explanation

```
 ?  I  -- if the input is truthy
  ∞    --   repeat it infinitly many times
   ;   --   else create singleton list
¶      -- join by newlines
```

Thanks @H.PWiz for golfing off 1 byte!

Comment: 5 bytes: `¶?∞;±` or, if string input is valid: `?∞;i`

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65ar7Zar6C2PCMzJ/X/fwMA) - 13 bytes

```
~{.}{.p}while
```

Basically a

```
while(arg){
    print(arg)
}
print(arg)
```

GolfScript doesn't have a real-time STDOUT, everything is printed from the stack to the console at the end of the execution, it has to be stopped manually.

Comment: Yes it does https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65ar7Zar6C2PCMzJ/X/fwMA

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 38 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
L	OUTPUT =N
	GT(N) :S(L)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hMuH0z80BMhQsPXj4nQP0fDTVLAK1vDR5HL1c/n/3wAA)

```
	N =INPUT	;* read input as n
L	OUTPUT =N	;* print input
	GT(N) :S(L)	;* if n > 0, goto L
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc) , 42 bytes

```
main(t){gets(&t);do puts(&t);while(t-48);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPo0SzOj21pFhDrUTTOiVfoaAUyi7PyMxJ1SjRNbHQtK79/98AAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 6 bytes

```
Iv=O=:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v/fs8zW39bq/39DAA)

#### Explanation

In Wumpus, the IP gets reflected off the program boundary (instead of wrapping around or terminating). Since there is no redirecting control flow in this program, the IP simply bounces back and forth, executing a loop with loop body

```
Iv=O=:=O=v
```

Let's go through this:

```
I   Read an integer N from STDIN. On subsequent iterations, this will push a zero.
v   Bitwise OR. On the first iteration this ORs the input with an implicit zero
    which does nothing. On subsequent iterations, this gets rid of the zero that
    was just pushed.
=   Duplicate the input.
O   Print it to STDOUT.
=   Duplicate it again.
:   Compute N/N. For input 0, this ends the program, due to the attempted division
    by zero. For input 1, this just gives back 1.
=   Duplicate the input.
O   Print it to STDOUT.
=   Duplicate the input.
v   Bitwise OR. Just gets rid of one copy of the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ShinyLisp](https://github.com/Mercerenies/shiny-lisp/), 22 bytes

```
+:Ge _&^:Pu~:I:P^~N:Qx
```

I figure now is as good a time as any to introduce my new golfing language. It's still largely a work in progress, but it's usable.

Ungolfed:

```
(= (gets))
(loop '% (puts) (cond (p %) () (quit)))
```

Explanation:

```
(= (gets))       -- Reads a line of user input and assigns it %
(loop '% ...)    -- Loop forever using % as the (constant) loop value
(puts)           -- Print the value of %
(cond (p %) ...) -- If % (treated as a number) is nonzero then...
()               -- Do nothing
(quit)           -- Else exit the program
```

Answer (score 1):

## Linotte, 52 bytes

```
a:
e est un nombre
début
demande e
e!
tant que e,e!
```

Linotte is a french programming language aimed at beginners. Translated into English:

```
a:
e is a number
start
ask for e
e!
while e, e!
```

`e!` is shorthand for `affiche e`, which means "display `e`".

[You can find a download here.](http://langagelinotte.free.fr/wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 42 bytes

```
READ*,I
DO
PRINT*,I
IF(I==0)EXIT
ENDDO
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8PcnV00dLx5HLx5woI8vQLAbE93TQ8bW0NNF0jPEO4XP1cgHJA8v9/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [TIS](https://github.com/Phlarx/tis.git) `-n` `1` `1`, 29 bytes

```
@0
ADD UP
L:MOV ACC ANY
JGZ L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ks/v/fwYDL0cVFITSAy8fK1z9MwdHZWcHRL5LLyz1Kwef/f4P/unn/Df8bAgA)

`ADD UP` is a shorter form of `MOV UP ACC`, since the accumulator starts at zero, and we only ever see one value on the input (if that is not desired +4 bytes to add `HCF` after the last line).

`MOV ACC ANY` simply does the output. This line is also labelled `L`.

`JGZ L` jumps to `L` if the accumulator is greater than zero. (`JNZ L`, jump if non-zero, would work identically here.)

In the case where we have a zero for input, we do not jump, but instead wrap around to the first line (`ADD UP`). Since there is no more data to be had, the system goes quiescent.

In the case of a one, we will endlessly jump to `L`, outputting a 1 on every third cycle (writing to a neighbor actually takes two cycles in TIS).

Answer (score 1):

## brainfuck, 25 bytes

**Note**: This is a different "language" than [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62846/70894), because it requires a brainfuck variant that exits when the memory pointer is moved left of the initial position, whereas this needs a brainfuck variant that can read and write left of the initial position.

```
,.[[<+>->+<]>-]<+[<<]>[.]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fRy862kbbTtdO2ybWTjfWRjvaBsiI1ov9/98AAA)

### Explanation

```
,.             Read and print a character.
[[<+>->+<]>-]  Write the range from the code point of the character down to one.
<+[<<]>        Go to the first element in the sequence if the length is odd, otherwise
                go to the cell before.
[.]            Print the value at the pointer forever if the input is odd, determined by
                if the pointer is on or outside the sequence of numbers in memory.
```

Here are two other interesting solutions i found, which may be golfable (29 bytes each):

```
,.+++[->+>+++++<<]>--->+[<.>]
,.[->+>+>--[<+>--]<<<]>>[<.>]
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 41 bytes

```
a=io.read()while q~="0"do print(a)q=a end
```

Explanation:

`a=io.read()`: read input from user and store in variable a

`while q~="0"do`: compares q to the string "0", q starts as nil, which isn't "0" so the loop runs at least once. Because the input is a string we have to compare with the string "0", not the number 0

`print(a)q=a`: prints a (1 or 0) and sets q to a, so if a = "1" the loop continues, if a = "0" the loop stops

`end`: end of loop, like `}` in other languages

Whitespace is not needed after parenthesis/quotation marks, for example `print(a)q=a` is equivalent to `print(a) q=a`

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [FerNANDo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 37 bytes

```
_ _ _ 1 _ _ _ _ C
C
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 C
C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0stykvMS8n//z9eAQQNFeKh0JnLmctAwQAoYqhgAIZAkf//DQA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 45 bytes

I just had the Eureka of this code:

```
x=int(raw_input())
print x
while x: print 1
```

I am proud of this one, though it may not look very impressive.

Comment: You don't need the indentation after `if x==1:`, also why not just do `if x:`?

Comment: @W W yeah I changed it. Also very late.

Comment: Change `int(raw_input)` to input() because Python 2's eval converts it automatically to int.

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 9 bytes

```
00000000: cd03 80ff fe30 20fb 76                   .....0 .v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSSUwyMFSwM0tIU0lKNDRSMDNKSFMzNFDCBHggYKOiVAXUDAA)

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  call $8003
loop:
  rst $38
  cp $30
  jr nz, loop
  halt
```

The Z80Golf machine initializes whole memory and all registers to zero before loading the program.

`call $8003` calls `getchar`, which takes a byte from stdin to register `a`. On EOF, the register `a` does not change and the carry flag is set.

`rst $38` simulates a call to `putchar` which prints the register `a`. The function is actually at `$8000`, so PC slides through `$00` bytes (NOPs) in the memory until it hits the address `$8000`.

The rest is just a straightforward do-while loop in assembly, no tricks involved.

---

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), Byte IO, 8 bytes

```
00000000: cd03 80ff b820 fc76                      ..... .v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSSUwyMFSwM0tIUkiyMDBTSks3NFLACPRBQ0Cv7/58RAA)

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  call $8003
loop:
  rst $38
  cp b
  jr nz, loop
  halt
```

The only difference is the use of `cp b`, where `b` is used in place of constant zero.

---

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), Byte IO, Tricky version, 8 bytes

```
00000000: cd03 80b8 2002 ff76                      .... ..v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSSUwyMFSwMkiwUjAwMjBTS0szNFLACPSAAEmX//zMCAA)

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  call $8003
  cp b
  jr nz, infinity
  rst $38
  halt
infinity:
```

If the input is zero, `rst $38` and then `halt` is executed, exiting the program normally. Otherwise, something weird happens:

- PC goes to `infinity:`, slides through NOPs, and then `putchar` is executed.
- The `putchar` has a `ret` instruction, so `sp` becomes 2 and execution is returned to the address `$03cd`.
- Then `putchar` is executed again. `sp` becomes 4, `pc` is `$b880`.
- Now `pc` wraps around and comes to `$0000`, the start of the program.
- `call $8003` is run, which overwrites the program so `$80b8` becomes `$0300`.
- `getchar` sets the carry flag, but we don't care anyway. EOF is hit so `a` is untouched.
- Now `cp b` became `nop`, but `jr nz, infinity` is intact. Again `putchar` is run, `sp` becomes 6, `pc` is `$0220`. `putchar` again, `sp = 8`, `pc` is `$76ff`, `putchar` again, `sp = 10 = $000a`, `pc = $0000`.
- The `call $8003` became `call $0303`, which now effectively calls `putchar` instead. No problem, now one loop just prints `a` twice. Note that a `call` leaves `$0300` to the memory, but fortunately `$00` is NOP and `$03` is `inc bc`, which does not affect the program's logic. (Single-byte `inc` does affect the flags, but double-byte ones don't, so `jr nz` isn't affected either.)
- The `call` is now a heat wave filling the memory with `$0300`. Eventually, `sp` wraps around to `$0002` again, and finally overwrites `$cd03` into `$0300`, deleting the `call` .

The heat wave is finally over, and the only thing left is:

```
  jr nz, infinity
  rst $38
  halt
infinity:
```

The conclusion is that we have an infinite loop printing `1` as a byte.

Note that `putchar` is NOT an actual piece of code in memory. It is "simulated" when the PC hits `$8000`, along the `ret` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 54 bytes

```pascal
var a:word;begin read(a);repeat write(a)until a<1 end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDoAgDAXQq3TUQRNW8TJfWgkJQVKrHL/6ttdxJ9Tl7Mn9hRK2cSnHQ3JppAKeMEeVLjAaWkz@P81KJeyBpPHqHj4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Little Man Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer), 19 bytes (4 instructions)

```
INP
OUT
BRZ 4
BRA 1
```

Which, when assembled into RAM, is:

```
901 902 704 601
```

Annoyingly, `BRP` means branch if positive **or zero**, making it useless for distinguishing between the two possible inputs. Therefore we have to use two seperate branching commands: `BRZ` (branch if zero) to escape the program, followed by a `BRA` (branch always) to continue the loop if the number is non-zero.

An online interactive interpreter can be found [here](https://peterhigginson.co.uk/lmc/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 9 bytes

```
{I>{@:1O_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/7/a067awcrQP/7/fwMA)

A little convoluted, but that's Backhand's way.

#### Explanation:

```
{I>{@:1O_
{           # Step left, bouncing off the wall and changing directions
 I          # Get input as a number
  >         # Enter loop by setting the direction to right
     :      # Dupe input
        _   # Step left if 1, otherwise right and change directions
       O    # Both output here, but are going in different directions
    @       # Terminate if 0
  >{  1     # Otherwise push 1 to the stack and restart the loop again
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 28 bytes

```
>>,.[[>]+<[-<]<+>>]>[<]<<[.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fzk5HLzraLlbbJlrXJtZG284u1i4ayLCJ1ov9/98AAA)

This should be portable to almost all implementations of brainfuck. If you don't mind negative cells, you can save 2 bytes by removing the initial `>>`.

#### Explanation:

```
 >>                # Go right
 ,.                # Get input and print it once
 [[>]+<[-<]<+>>]   # Convert the number to binary while preserving it
 >[<]<<            # If the last digit of the binary is odd
 [.]               # Print the input forever
```

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 10 bytes

```
*0_+!#(!#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P9fyyBeW1FZQ1FZ8/9/QwA)

### Explanation

```
*0_+!#(!#)
*             take byte of input
 0            push 48
  _+          subtract
    !#        duplicate and output
      (  )    while the top of the stack is not 0:
       !#     duplicate and output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 24 bytes

```
_->In_a+Out_a
a->a+Out_a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XtfOMy8@Udu/tCQ@kStR1w7K/P/fAAA)

I couldn't figure out a shorter way using only one output section. The closest I came was [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XtfOMy8@UbuKq0rXzr@0JD6RK1HXDsj//98AAA)

#### Explanation:

```
_->In_a            # a = input
       +Out_a      # Output a
a->a               # While a
    +Out_a         # Output a
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 5 bytes

```
IZh1n
```

Thanks to JoKing for helping golf this down further!!!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zMqwzDv/39DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tamsin](https://github.com/catseye/Tamsin), 19 bytes

```
main="0"|{print 1}.
```

### Explanation

The `main` production first tries to read a `0`. If it succeeds, it is returned, and, because this is the main production, printed.

Otherwise, it ignores the input and tries the alternative, which is `{print 1}`. The `{ }` brackets denote a loop that continues running as long as its content succeeds, and a `print` statement always succeeds, so this loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

### [Eukleides](http://eukleides.org), 40 bytes

```
a=number();for i=0to 0;print a;i=i-a;end
```

Pretty straightforward. `number()` takes in a number as input. For loop *seems* to be the golfiest means of looping for this task. While loop skips the `i=i-a;` but requires two `print`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
a=input()
while(a=='1'):print(1)
print(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSPR1lbdUF3TqqAoM69Ew1CTC8Iw0Pz/3wAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 89 bytes

```
DOWRITEIN.1PLEASE.3<-#1$.1DOCOMEFROM(2)DOREADOUT.1(2)PLEASE(1)NEXT(1)DO(1022)NEXTDOGIVEUP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FPzzIM8TV00/PMMDH1THYVc/YRlfZUEXP0MXf2d/X1S3I31fDSNPFP8jV0cU/NETPEMiDqNQw1PRzjQgBUi7@GoYGRkZgrou/u2eYa2jA///@fq5cAA)

Looking at some answers to this challenge, I noticed that the current INTERCAL answer was barely golfed at all, with 141 bytes 30 of which are whitespace. Not hard to outdo!

Uses native INTERCAL-72 integer I/O, that is, the input is `ZERO` or `ONE` (or some translation thereof) with a trailing newline, and the output is in "butchered Roman numerals".

Explanation:

`DO WRITE IN .1`

Inputs a number to the 16-bit variable `.1`.

`PLEASE .3 <- #1 $ .1`

Sets `.3`'s value to 1 mingled with `.1`'s value. Since `.1` holds either 0 or 1, `.3` is set to either 2 or 3.

`DO COME FROM (2)`

If execution would move on normally from statement `(2)`, it goes here instead.

`DO READ OUT .1`

Prints the value in `.1`.

`(2) PLEASE (1) NEXT`

This is statement `(2)`. It places itself on the `NEXT` stack and moves execution to statement `(1)`. It does not trigger the `COME FROM` unless `RESUME`d to.

`(1) DO (1022) NEXT`

This is statement `(1)`. It `NEXTS` to statement `(1022)` in syslib, which then itself `NEXTS` to statement `(1023)` in syslib, which reads `PLEASE RESUME .3`. This pops a non-zero number of entries equal to `.3` off the `NEXT` stack and resumes execution at the last one popped. Since there are at this point three entries on the `NEXT` stack, corresponding to `(2)`, `(1)`, and `(1022)` (`RESUME` works just fine without labels, it just so happens that all of the `NEXT`s here have them), and `.3` is 2 or 3 depending on whether `.1` is 0 or 1, this goes to and moves on from either `(1)` if `.1` is 0, or `(2)` if `.1` is 1. If this `RESUME`s to `(2)`, the `COME FROM` takes effect and begins an infinite loop (and since this outcome leaves the `NEXT` stack empty, the program does not disappear into the black lagoon after 80 loops).

`DO GIVE UP`

If `(1)` was `RESUME`d to, execution moves here, and this terminates the program without an error.

(I'll edit in a version with Turing Tape string I/O some time later.)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 13 bytes

```
~{.}{.p}while
```

#### Explanation

```
~       # convert STDIN to an integer

{.}     # while loop condition: remains the same--the input
{.p}    # while loop body: print the input
while
```

<sup>This is one of my first golfs!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg#While_Loops), <del>12</del> <del>8</del> <del>7</del> 4 bytes

```
{:|④
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fKrraSu//fwMA)

### Explanation

```
# Implicit input
{:|  # While the duplicated item is nonzero:
   ④ # Output the item without popping
     # After that, Output the item remaining on the stack and stop the program
```

Comment: This can now be [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///fKrraSq@2Ru//f0MA) due to implicit input

Comment: 4 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/2qrm0cTF//8bAgA "Keg – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### [Enterprise](https://github.com/joaomilho/Enterprise), 128 bytes

```
/©©//NDANDA/final disruptive class fdcBit{final immutable void main(){var Money i=read();;;write(i);;;while(i==1){write(i);;;}}}
```

It's really annoying how the specification isn't very clear, so I had to guess a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

```
IqW1P1i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fszDcMMAw8/9/AwA)

explanation:

```
If(q) // q is input
    While(1) {
        print(1);
    }
output 0  // i is initialized to 0, but this stops it from being confused for "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 10 bytes

```
?1/
#?
&#|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/395Qn0vZnktNueb/f0MA)

My first submission with my new language Cascade! Cascade is a tree-like esolang, similar to [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), but a bit terser and with wrapping boundaries. Ungolfed, this looks more like:

```
 @ |
 ? /
 #|
 &|
  ^
 # |
 1 |
```

First, the `?` checks if the printed (`#`) input (`&`) is positive. If not, it goes left and terminates since it finds no more instructions. If so, it goes right to the `^`, which first executes the left (`#1`, print 1), then goes to the right, which wraps around back to the `^` for an infinite loop. In the golfed code we use another `?` which does a similar thing except with the center and the right, since we know the return value of `#` is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
:p↺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/36rgUduu//8NAA)

#### Explanation

```
  ↺  While...
:    Duplicating the top of stack leaves a true value on top:
 p   Print the top of the stack
```

Input is taken implicitly in Gaia. Every iteration leaves the stack empty, but if there is no input left when it attempts to grab some, it simply takes the most recently given input again.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 35 bytes

```
a=input()
while a:a=int(a);print(a)
```

This is the best I can do, don't know if it's the optimal solution though.

### Explanation

In Python 3, `input()` stores the input as a string, so even if the user types `0`, it will be stored as `'0'`, which is truthy. This allows me to make a kind of do-while loop, which will always run at least once since `'0'` and `'1'` are both truthy. However, I then convert `a` to an integer (`'0'` becomes `0` and `'1'` becomes `1`). Now, if the user typed `0`, it will not run again since the while loop is now `while 0` and `0` is falsy. However, if the user typed `1`, it will run forever since the while loop is now `while 1` and `1` is truthy.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSHRqqAoM69EI9HKFkxpav7/bwgA)

Comment: @a'_' oh nice, didn't know that was a thing in Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <s>39</s> 32 Bytes

```
x=+prompt();do{alert(x)}while(x)
```

`x=+prompt()` gets input from user, and transforms it from a string to a number

`do{alert(x)}while(x)`  is a post test loop, so it always alerts X, then executes again if x not = 0

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), <s>19</s> <s>29</s> 19 bytes

```
0 0 * * h
0 * 1 r 0
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?5ba150b2b0a59c0b364e14d1231ec213)

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to @Laikoni*

Comment: This is doable with just two rules: `0 0 * * h` and `0 * 1 r 0`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Comp](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Comp), 6 or 8 bytes

The first golfing language (sort of :) ) from 2020!

```
;{^&}&
```

That could be a mistake. An alternative program is:

```
;{^£}£
```

### Explanation

```
;      Take an input from the console as an integer
 {^£}  While that's nonzero, duplicate & print
     £ If that's zero, directly print
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python3, **40Bytes**

```
a=input()
while int(a):print(a)
print(a)
```

- If input is 0 it will be printed once.
- If input is 1 it will be printed forever.

Answer (score 1):

### [RAKIAC](https://github.com/Roninkoi/RAKIAC) machine language, 6 bytes (34 real for asm)

```
00000100
00000011
00110100
00100001
00000001
00000010
```

Representing the assembly:

```
in
s: out
jez v
jmp s
v: hlt
end
```

Tried out one of my things for fun (definitely not made for golf).

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [4 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
“l○|
```

## Explained

Unpacked: `&&[{1`

Takes advantage of the fact that Arn's interpreter is written in Javascript. This means the `&&` and `||` operator can be used as control flow.

```
  _     % Variable initialized to STDIN. Implied
&&      % Boolean AND
  [     % Sequence
    {   % Block; used to calculate future entries in a sequence
      1 % Literal one
    }   % End block. Implied
  ]     % End sequence. Implied
```

Comment: One more answer and I'm going to learn Arn.

Comment: ;) haha, like your esolang 1+ a lot too

Comment: (Although, common mistake is I created 1+ - Parcly Taxel created it.)

Comment: Oh wow, you use it so much I assumed it was yours haha. Apologies to the creator then.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 8 bytes

Uses the `-n` flag to suppress printing without an explicit `p` command.

```
:
p
/1/b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f/fiquAS99QP@n/f4N/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Commented:

```
#create an unnamed label
:
#print pattern space
p
#If pattern space contains 1, branch to beginning
/1/b
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 137 bytes

```
TRUTHFUL MACHINE
A:I=true,O=false
B:get a number or get a value
C:if falsy,a zero
D:if truthy,a one
D.a:repeat it if value=I
E:suspend it
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?JYxbCsIwFET/7yruAorgbyAffUkDakHaBdzSGy3UpOQh6OZrQmF@5nBmhsc4dJfxirey7tS9hVIoGVzkopeaVs9QiScHJDTxPbFD6/DoH1ojQy0WjVn8FoQ/dhaaTNJDeGVkDUNzIuF4Ywq4pOhjKhW0wke/sZkT38/7RPMf)

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 40 bytes

```python
a=int(input())
while a:
  print(a)
print(a)
```

This is simple but effective. A fun thing about this is that while we could put a condition that a==1 in, this is more fun because it reuses a, and a will be 1 causing the loop to run forever (works with any a != 0)

Answer (score 1):

## [10IPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/10IPL), 34 bytes

```
11001000 01001100 00100010 10100001 10100100 00100010 10100001 10100100 00100010 10100001 10100100 00100010 10100001 10100100 00100010 10100001 10100100 00100010 10100001 10100100 00100010 10100001 00100010 00011010 00101010 00101010 00101010 00101010 00101010 00000100 00000100 00000100 00110010 11110000
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/10IPL?p=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)

**Program:**

```
; input

inp rp0

; r1

xor r1, rp0

; rp0 OR r1

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
nor rp0, rp0

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
nor rp0, rp0

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
nor rp0, rp0

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
nor rp0, rp0

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
nor rp0, rp0

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
nor rp0, rp0

rtr r1
nor rp0, r1
rtr r1

; pointer

inr rp1
rtr rp1
rtr rp1
rtr rp1
rtr rp1
rtr rp1
zro r2
zro r2
zro r2

; print

prt r1

; jump

jmp
```

**What is 10IPL?**

10IPL, short for 10 Instruction Programming Language, is a simple compiled language I made for use in a computer I'm building in Minecraft. I made an online interpreter for it (with a few extra features), since I think it's a neat language.

**How does this work?**

This program consists of a few parts:

1. Take input
2. Set `rp0` (the upper 8 bits of a pointer) to either `00000000` (if the input is truthy) or `11111111` (if the input is falsy)
3. Set `rp1` (the lower 8 bits of the pointer) to point to the `prt` instruction after it
4. Print the inputted value
5. Jump to the pointer

This will jump into a few KiB of zeroed out RAM if the input is `00000000`, then terminate. Otherwise, it keep going forever. Don't try it online.

Answer (score 1):

### [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 16 bytes

```
, +'. '` +. +' `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fR0FbXU9BPUFBWw/IUkj4/98IAA)

Pretty simple, it reads the input onto the stack, if it's zero, it prints it, and if it's non-zero, prints it forever.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ocaml, 46 bytes

```ocaml
let a=read_int()in while print_int a;a=1 do 0
```

urk the functions name and the control flow takes a lot of chars.
The trick since there is no do-while is to put the print *directly in the condition*
(sometime ago when I did that in a course lab, the teach called me a "connoisseur of monstrosities" (approx tl))

The 0 in the end causes a warning, so you need to disable werror.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 13 bytes

```
:l;s/1/1/p;tl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/3yrHuljfEAgLrEty/v83BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [yuno](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno), 4 bytes

```
ᴀ_¹¿
```

[Try it online!](https://yuno.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIiLCLhtIBfwrnCvyIsIiIsIiIsIlciLFsiMCJdXQ==)

Or, using the flag to disable implicit output:

## [yuno](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno) `d`, 3 bytes

```
ᴀ_¿
```

[Try it online!](https://yuno.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIiLCLhtIBfwr8iLCIiLCIiLCJXZCIsWyIxIl1d)

### Explanation

The `W` flag caps output at 10,000 characters just so it doesn't freeze your browser window for too long.

```
ᴀ_¹¿    Main Link
   ¿    While
  ¹     The element is truthy
ᴀ_      Output it
        <Implicitly output the value>

ᴀ_¿     Main Link
  ¿     While
ᴀ_      Output the element, then assess if it's truthy
        <d flag disables implicit output>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), 49 bytes.

```
}{*|*^__________!||_^_____________*{___^___****!*
```

### Usage

- Input from STDIN, as an ASCII number character.
- Output to STDOUT, in ASCII.

### With comments

```
(
0: }{*|*^
'*'+1: ****!* 

'*'+1: * changed to 48-42or49-42 by |:
   12 10t - 11 20t is 01 20t is 15
   12 11t - 11 20t is 01 21t is 16 

'*'+2: * for * command 

'*'+1: 15or16 for ^ 

15+1: ! reaches when zero
16+1: ||^ reaches when one 

obtw '*'+3: * and '*'+4: * are for | to have the register A have 49 again 

'*'+5: ! for ^ 

After that '*'+4: '1' BUT whatever 

'!'+1: *{___^ repeatedly output one 

* 42 ! 33 

) 

(
0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789
)
}{*|*^____ ______!||_ ^_________ ____*{___^
(
0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789
)
___****!*
```

[Try with 0!](https://tio.run/##jVb/U@I4FP@9f8WzIrQg2wLqLXbjnIverTOe7qh7c3eCndgG6FEapgnKLvC3ey9tQWh1bjPTNvn0fc97LxmJ4cuuH4gPbPz4YcJFMAvEGJp2s2EfNVvwr5CaYBLqbKpNx1SMwLabTY3NJjyWcNlxTy8vSUebg/w@YTBg0uNRv1xOVh4fj2nka8sTy2dPVjQNQ2ielBvlcsb@9fTuC9FLRkYI9clKQvLLLM3Vp3a8TCfH9aW@0vz1@vbir8u/3c71zc1554404NvVxV/u7d0Zadp2S7sHvTT/fHr7xf3z/Ob24vpKMUOvXE6c4ZB4mq5qn1Pqf4rEbDwNqWQghgkpn0icPvPYF5MwkOUyDQMqoD6ASmneqOmlX/VlhVTUt1IuX327vOz8cUaOE/GGUuU7Yhj0pZPMQdFlAPOGHEq7pg4EGkqzsQMJVvkaMioYTPGJ2DOL0QAWhhWzcVLGbXiiIeg70KehYPpi8XNciTkJ3WwhmA8VYc2s75Yj8PXDqiRG/IDe2@Juv90@tWqAfJk0zB0Re8k2UvnpU8V1WeSeuRVnEgeR7IP7spxXF9UHdz12Fgt3Y4mjOseXgqo4dqovmQzN1LVd6AexkCCfOYRBxATwPvQ5l@gUfeRPTNPGbKzUawCQ6dwTakNTy/Zc3MuF@oljF2I2RiYQE@qhLDbzGG7q5W8iI5Ax1DEiXdl96va7MVQ2WFWaskhmIuIMTyKYzY/pCrSM@wezp56qaVmDDLYMa55NcZQeX@dXr9PHlZDlpnLJAZ3Jln0eYrU8N9b/BzGbwIf1kj6P1jZ9Pv/94mpDq8enkSS284rwSXyvV/UeOWjm0QdE2wd59ATRowLtAtFGs0A8T@BWHl4m8GEedpXCArqDaGstYpl9SzYEkSLY8C7oG6mD5LBtH7TNjV@r9AA9iCZTiXkVMgwrphWPBmg9pi@ojNadLR42CxDfwJZaTp4ysWT3nFyMa7WiwYTohj7PC9Cn0ZhKb4iZZLxjyLYVK4E7xjoGZlHqhpvYUyUNIoHE2DICH7whjamHRSR@TiF2BS2pxYiG4XcUg6yTmOFb4/7jgNjAH6d90tAMbV2D3W6EZYjViV1btRGGZwHHvD2FCOpPUJcwzTJYVV1HgI15cnB49MvHtmKt3Hejai@rgTTBNTNdqfxGCTOJPjDUjfNnGkcun0red7mH@Z3m/1byB1nWJ9Gz0Jp1MVLiEf@1Jvo8NhxnM6Idgm7ce5t7jJmW6s/lmOcSz/Fd4jtvpR4Wrr5P9719f7@zr2T6vbfjv5Flu4DVuaW4Q7BWzS35Pqml4pwtxocCY/tgm9F7m/GkwHiU00hJykfQMSOdWi0zE7bXqjbaRx9b20IXBaHYMHLxC7Z6U7YbI9JwRp@UxANnVCWtbUsUV40Yyg5qjcy9Vn3DJLWutfBVHTnv2P9u2Odv2JvTjTBNm83HglFJDeW8YXhSK6btfMWrxEnz8LAgIcuauzjA3oBHQLLGBHq/W6H4N4X0Qe/i2OPdCPm3t2X5hpuHBTfxaqYOYKCfiF0wlKYh2Jbr6sftQ1A3Oy6H2GqAxngf4ZMtop2C8lYuxIUwvld6WbTwxrOqsaRq3V5aafi9vrn933LziOHVGuZe3iGfGH4BX64bysoUpSrokdLa4CA7CNRxDp66R5VUy1R920gDmYHYQDMQEek4RtVcH/9PNIZQde1ogJngT9XJBRLbKuAlB1c8AhnwjeMfW2JIDuz2Ue4iQLG8BNF1JySh1aw3mivPQxYN5NAQROA5ZZ6QcJ6GUzgrlozy/Ops9QtdUpjjMEG9pDPPaDzAG/EFzFZpN9MST1KXFN2L/R8)

[Try with 1!](https://tio.run/##jVb/U@I4FP@9f8WzIrQgW76ot1jDrIverTOe7qh7s3eCndgG6FEapgnKLvC3ey9tQWh1bjPTNvn0fc97LxmJ4cuu54sPbPz4YcKFP/PFGBq1Rr121GjCv0Jqgkmosqk2HVMxglqt0dDYbMIjCZcd5/TyknS0OcgfEwYDJl0e9ovFeOXy8ZiGnrZsWx57ssJpEECjXawXiyn719O7L0QvGCkhVCcrCfEvszBXn8rxMpkcV5f6SvPX69uL75d/O53rm5vzzh2pw7eri@/O7d0ZadRqTe0e9ML88@ntF@ev85vbi@srxQy9YjF2hkPsabKqfE6o/8kTs/E0oJKBGMakfCJx@swjT0wCXxaLNPCpgOoASoV5vaIXPunLEimpb6lYvPp2edn584wcx@INpcqzxdDvSzueg6JLAeYOORR2TR0I1JVmYwdirPQ1YFQwmOITsmcWoQEsCEpmvV3EbXiiAeg70KeBYPpi8WtcsTkx3WwhmAclYc2sH5Yt8PXTKsVG/ITe2@Juv90@NSuAfKk0zB0RufE2UnlyUnIcFjpnTsmeRH4o@@C8LOflRfnBWY@dxcLZWOIoz/GloDKOnfJLKkMzdW0X@n4kJMhnDoEfMgG8D33OJTpFH/kT07QxGyv1GgCkOveE2tDEsj0H93KhfuLYhYiNkQnEhLooi81chpt6@btICWQEVYxIV3afuv1uBKUNVpWmLJSpiCjF4wim82O6Ai3j/sHsqadsWtYghS3DmqdTHIXH1/nV6/RxJWS5qVxyQGfSZZ8HWC3P9fX/QcQm8GG9pM@jtU2fz/@4uNrQ6vJpKEnNfkX4JLrXy3qPHDSy6AOirYMs2kb0KEe7QLTeyBHPY7iZhZcxfJiFHaUwh@4g2lyLWKbfQg38UBFseOf3jcRBctiqHbTMjV@r9ADdDydTiXkVMAwrphUPB2g9pi@ojNbtLR428xHfwJZaRp4ysVDr2ZkYVyp5gwnRDX2eFaBPwzGV7hAzyXjHkG0rVgJ3jHUMzLzUDTexp0rqhwKJsWX4HrhDGlEXi0j8mkLsClpciyENgh8oBlknEcO3xr3HAakBf5z2SV0ztHUNdrshliFWJ3Zt1UYYngUc8/YUQqg@QVXCNM1gVXUdATXMk4PDo98@thRr6b4blntpDSQJrpnJSuU3SphJ9IGhbpw/0yh0@FTyvsNdzO8k/7eS30@zPo6ehdasi5ESl3ivNdHnkWHbmxHtEHTj3t3cY8y0RH8mx1yHuLbnEM9@K/WwcPV9uu/ue/udfSXT670d/40s2wWszi3FHYK1am7J90glEWdvMT7kGFsH24zu24ztHONRRiMlCR9Bx4xkajXNVNhes1xvHX1sbgtd5IRiw8jEz9/qTelujEjdHp0oiQf2qEya25YorgoxlB3UGpl7zeqGSWpdaeKrPLLfsf/dsM/fsDejG2GaNJuPOaPiGsp4w/CkVkzb@YpXiXbj8DAnIc2au8jH3oBHQLzGBHq/W6H4N4X0Qe/i2OPdEPm3t2X5hpuHOTfxaqYOYKAnpJYzlCYh2Jbr6MetQ1A3Oy6H2GqARngf4ZMtop2c8mYmxLkwvld6abTwxrOqsbhqnV5Safi9vrn933JzieFW6uZe1iGPGF4OX64bysoUpcrvkcLaYD89CNRxDq66RxVUy1R920gCmYLYQFMQEWnbRtlcH/9PNIJAde1wgJngTdXJBRLbKuAlB1c8BOnzjeMfW2JADmqto8xFgGJ5CaLrdkACq1GtN1aeBywcyKEhiMBzymyTYJ6EU9grlpTy/Ops9QtdUphtM0HduDPPaDTAG/EFzFZpN9NiTxKXFN1L/T8)

Comment: I think I can golf more.

Answer (score 1):

## [Mascarpone](https://github.com/catseye/Mascarpone), 18.125 bytes

```
['1.:!]v*['0.]v*1[:!]v*'1<,>!
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y00sTk4sKsjPS/3/P1rdUM9KMbZMK1rdQA9IGUaDeeqGNjp2iv//AwA)

I'm surprised to see so few Mascarpone answers even on the big questions like this.  It's a shame, it's such a beautiful language even if it is a bit of a tarpit.

Answer (score 1):

### Arduino, <s>133</s> <s>129</s> 117 bytes

Thanks to **@tail spark rabbit ear** for shaving off 12 bytes!

```
#define S Serial
int x=0;void setup(){S.begin(300);}void loop(){S.available()&&S.print(x=S.read()-48);x&&S.print(1);}
```

Arduino is basically C++, but with this bit implied:

```
int main() {
  setup();
  while (true) {
    loop();
  }
  return 0; // to make the compiler happy, I guess
}
```

The `setup()` and `loop()` functions must be implemented.
Explanation:

```
#define S Serial /* macro to make referencing the Serial monitor shorter */
int x = 0; // must either be global, or declared `static` inside `loop()`

void setup() {
  S.begin(300);
  // The argument to Serial.begin() is the baud rate
  // 300 is the slowest supported option, but therefore takes the fewest bytes
}

void loop() {
  S.available() &&
    // Serial.available() returns truthy when there are unread bytes from the serial input
    // Using && as a shortcut for an if statement (like minified JS)

    S.print(
      x = S.read() - 48
    );
    // Serial.read() dequeues the next byte from the input
    // 48 is ASCII '0'
    // Serial.print() converts 0 back to "0"; Serial.write() wouldn't

  x &&
    S.print(1);
}
```

As `loop()` is called indefinitely, it's impossible to terminate, so inputting "0" settles into a loop that prints nothing until something else is input.

Original:

```
int x=0;void setup(){Serial.begin(300);}void loop(){if(Serial.available()){x=Serial.read()-48;Serial.print(x);}if(x)Serial.print(1);}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Would it be possible for you to provide either a link to the language, or a link to a testing environment, so that others can run your code?

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Unfortunately no. In order to run Arduino code you have to deploy it to a physical Arduino board.

Comment: [117 bytes: does this work well?](https://tio.run/##RcxBCsMgEADAe18hFMJ6iFjaQ0Hyin3BRrdhQVRsEoTSt9vQHnoeGF/KuHjf@znwQxIrVMhVKJ4krapN1u1ZgnryuhXQLzQzL5Lgaq127y/FnH9CO0mkOTLoYUBT6jFAm9BUpgB6vN21a3@5HEHvHw)

Answer (score 1):

## n/t/roff, 27 bytes.

```
.de a
\\$1
.if \\$1 .a 1
..
```

Defines a macro `a`.

### Usage

```
.a 0
.a 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@J9XlJ@WpmBjo54IBOr/9VJSFRK5YmJUDLn0MtMUQAwFvUQFIE/vP5A24AJzQGr/AwA)

Comment: No wait I need to modify to accept from STDIN, not from macro argument.

Comment: How the hell can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 32 + 1 = 33 bytes

The 1-byte penalty is for filename specification; the following program must be saved as `x`.

```bash
((x))||read x
echo $x
((x))&&. x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkpiZo6BrrKBiYFfBlVqRmqyQBBRWqPivoVGhqVlTU5SamKIAlEnOyFdQqeACi6qp6QEV/DcAAA)

### Tracing how it works

- The variable x is not initialized.
- `((x))` evaluates to `((0))`: command is failure.
- So `read x` is done.
- Then `echo $x`.
- Final line is for branching.

  - If `x` is zero, the program ends.
  - If `x` is one, `. x` is done.

    - It loads the file `x`: the program itself.
    - First command evaluates to `((1))` so no more `read`ing.
    - Then rest two lines are executed and it loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

## BASH

```
read a; [ $a -eq 0 ] && echo 0 || ( [ $a -eq 1 ] && while true; do echo 1; done )
```

Comment: Testing now. may need tweaked

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Please [edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/237348/edit) your answer to include the language (I'm guessing Bash?) and byte count

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks. Forgot the `$`s as well. Added. How do we get count? Is it count as in ascii? If its in the link, I'm reading now. Thanks again. EDIT: Wait a char is 2 bytes on X64, no?

Comment: I believe most Bash answers simply count the number of ascii bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), <s>34</s> 16 bytes

My original version was written back when I first made APOL and used none of the newer convenience instructions.

`¿(⧣ w(T p(1)) 0)`

### Explanation

```
¿(          Returning if
  ⧣         Integer input (used as condition, 0 evaluates to false)
  w(T       While true (true condition)
    p(1)    Print 1
  )
  0         A literal 0 (false condition)
)
Implicit print (¿ returns 0 if input is 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes

```
i=input;until(!i,print(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P9M2M6@gtMS6NK8kM0dDMVOnoCgzr0QjU1Pz/38DAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Applesoft BASIC, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
1INPUTA
2PRINTA
3IFA GOTO2
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Node.js), 54 bytes

A JavaScript answer that actually uses both STDIN and STDOUT

```js
n=process.argv[2];do{process.stdout.write(n)}while(+n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 28 bytes

```
:-get(X),repeat,put(X),X=48.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30o3PbVEI0JTpyi1IDWxRKegFMyLsDWx0Pv/3wAA)

Gets a single character, then repeatedly print it, stopping if it is a zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ᶦP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FkseblsWsKQ4KbkYKrBgoSGEAQA)

```
ᶦ    Iterate the following function zero or more times until it fails
 P   Check if the input is positive
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 28 bytes

```
s=io.read()while(-print(s))a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/7/YNjNfryg1MUVDszwjMydVQ7egKDOvRKNYUzPx/39DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(ß
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWizUOz19SnJRcDOUvWGgIYQAA)

```
    # implicit input
(   # while TOS is not 0:
 ß  #  print without popping
    # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tsept v1.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Tsept), 45 bytes

Tsept is an open-source esolang I created; it's not really meant for code golfing, as even basic tasks like setting a register to a number take many instructions, and even though there are seven different registers it's almost impossible to do anything without the stacks.

```
?PBKpPxIIIPAPAPAPABpBPBSPBxDDPAPADPBKB!BKBPBi
```

Note that you'll need a Linux machine to run this since there is no web-based interpreter for it (yet).

### Analysis

```
?PBKpPxIIIPAPAPAPABpBPBSPBxDDPAPADPBKB!BKBPBi
?PBKpP                                        Store input in register B
      xIIIPAPAPAPA                            Set accumulator to 48
                  BpBPB                       Swap stack value and accumulator
                       SP                     Subtract ASCII 1 from accumulator and push to stack
                         BxDDPAPADPB          Calculate jump offset
                                    KB!BKBPBi Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)) 63 Chars or \$63\log_{256}(3)\approx\$ 12.48 Bytes

This was quite fun, kudos to [Dadsdy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/118038/dadsdy) for creating this language!

```
((),((())))(()(),(()())()(),,,(()),(()()))(,,,(()),(()()),(()))
```

[Try it!](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=((),((())))(()(),(()())()(),,,(()),(()()))(,,,(()),(()()),(()))&stdin=1&)

### Explanation

```
Set var_1 to the ascii value of the input (48 or 49)
((),((())))

var_2 = var_2 + 2; repeat while var_1 > var_2
(()(),(()())()(),,,(()),(()()))

print var_1; repeat while var_2 > var_1
(,,,(()),(()()),(()))
```

In practice this counts up in twos until var_2 becomes at least as big as the input. If the input was `0` (ascii 48) var_2 will be 48 and the last loop will run only once, if the input was `1` (ascii 49) var_2 will be 50 and the last loop will never terminate.

Comment: The behaviour of the loop executing only once if the conditions are equal is pretty helpful

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)), 46 bytes

```
((),(((()))(())),,,(),,((())))(,,(()),,((())))
```

[Try it online!](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=((),(((()))(())),,,(),,((())))(,,(()),,((())))&stdin=1)

Outputs separated by newlines.I also have an alternative [46 byter](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=((),((()))(()),,,(),,((()))())(,,(())(),,(()))&stdin=0) using a similar strategy.

#### Explanation:

Note that the `var` shorthand below will return -1 for `0` (representing EOF) and 1 for `-1`, otherwise the value stored at that index (default 0).

```
((),(((()))(())),,,(),,((())))   First expression
 ()               Set var1
   ,(((()))(()))  To var(var(var(1))+var(1))
                  So when var(1) maps to:
                    0 -> var(var(0)+0) = var(-1+0) = 1
                    1 -> var(var(1)+1) = var(1+1)  = 0
                  basically alternating between 0 and 1 each loop
                  my other solution flips between 0 and -1 instead
                ,,,(),           Repeat while 1>-1
                      ((()))     A maximum of input char times
(,,(()),,((())))  Second expression
 ,,(())           Output var1
       ,,((()))   Execute once if var(var(1)) == -1
                  And repeat forever if var(var(1)) > -1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thue++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/thue++), 17 bytes

```
0::=~0
(?=1)::=~1
```

Input is the state string, output is the alerts.

Answer (score 1):

## [MaybeLater](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/MaybeLater), 48 bytes

```
whenx is1{write(1)when0spass x=1}write(x=read())
```

One could remove `when0spass`  for 37 bytes, though doing so causes a stack-overflow pretty quickly.

A Pretty Canonical MaybeLater answer, hooks to `x` being assigned to `1` by writing a 1 and setting x to 1 again, causing an infinite loop. `when 0 seconds pass` is required to avoid recursion errors by using the event queue instead. Either way, writes the result of the read.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02sTErNSSxJLfr/vzwjNa9CIbPYsLq8KLMkVcNQEyRiUFyQWFysUGFrWAsRrrAtSk1M0dDU/P/fEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Shenzhen I/O, 51 bytes, 3¥, 5 Lines

```
@mov p0 acc
teq acc 0
+mov 0 x1
+mov 0 x0
-mov 1 x1
```

Takes an input on p0 and outputs to a LCD at x1. If the input is 0, writes to an unconnected XBus wire and will wait indefinitely (this is the closest to terminating that I can think of). If the input is non-zero, loops forever writing 1.

Here is a screenshot of the two cases simultaneously.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [><x>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dead_fish), 105 bytes

```
lddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddn?v
                                                 >n<
```

Comment: Welcome codegolf @none1 ; This is a nice try.

Comment: @none1 [16 byte version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267177/76374)

Answer (score 1):

## [><x>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dead_fish), <s>16</s> 9 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Bubbler

Abuses the fact that after every instruction, the accumulator is bound to [0, 255]. This allows us to just square the input until it's 0 or 1. Thankfully, ASCII "0", `48`, takes only one square to equal `0`, and ASCII "1" needs just 4 to equal `1`
.

```
lssss>n?<
```

Comment: I think `lssss>n?<` works.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-n`, 10 bytes

To avoid the [expensive loop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229339), duplicate the line and use `D` for looping:

```
h
G
P
/1/D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/P4PLnSuAS99Q3@X/f8N/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Answer (score 1):

### [ELVM IR](https://github.com/shinh/elvm), 50 bytes

```
getc A
mov B,A
sub A,48
.x:
putc B
jeq .x,A,1
exit
```

Explanation:

```
getc A     - Input A as ASCII
mov B,A    - Copy A to B
sub A,48   - Subtract A by 48, which converts ASCII to number, while B still stores the ASCII
.x:
putc B     - Output B (The ASCII)
jeq .x,A,1 - If A (The number) is equal to 1, jump to .x
exit       - Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Chef](http://search.cpan.org/%7Esmueller/Acme-Chef/), 179 bytes

```
a.

Ingredients.
0 a
1 b

Method.
Take a from refrigerator.
V the a.
Put b into 3rd mixing bowl.
Pour contents of the 3rd mixing bowl into the baking dish.
V until ved.

Serves 1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xDsIwEAT7e8W@wCLiFRRISCB6Jz7HVhKfdLkEfm9i6Gh3dlY7JI61ekd0KaNyyFxsdXSCpw490ZUtSXD08BPDI6osUI6aR1Zvoo6esHQgR7fN0CMXE5w1YMnvXEb08poPJptikGJtHhK/zl/rpzbQ@6mFIa@p7W/F8oydjxt0Z915Redq7T4)

A test of my new [REDACTED] compiler. As Chef always prints values only at program termination, this *technically* doesn't fulfill the requirements, but the baking pan (the thing that has the output) *does* fill up with infinite 1s so it technically counts. Here's the original code as a teaser:

```
def $in;
read $in;
while $in { print 1; flush; };
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), 5 bytes

```
"[']'
```

`"`     - input

`[ ]`  - while loop

`' '` - output

Answer (score 0):

## Lua For windows, 70 bytes

Use lua for windows for this

```
I=io.read() If I=="1" then while 1 do print"1" end elseif print"0" end
```

This program works because it takes a 0 or 1 from stdin then if it's a one it makes a while loop that prints one if it's a 0 it prints 0 then the program ends

Comment: Does this rely on functionality specific to Windows? Why couldn't this be run with Lua on other systems?

Comment: This could be shorter if you just called `If io.read()=="1"` instead of assigning it to an alias.

Answer (score 0):

### Ceylon, <s>91</s> 88 bytes

Improved (explanation at the end):

`shared void run()=>("0"<(process.readLine()else"")then{1}.cycled else{0}).each(print);`

This was the original (91 bytes):

`shared void run(){if("0"<(process.readLine()else"")){while(0<1){print(1);}}else{print(0);}}`

Unfortunately the most part goes to reading the input and making sure it is defined.

```
shared void run() {
    if("0"<(process.readLine() else "")) {
        while(0<1) {
            print(1);
        }
    } else {
        print(0);
    }
}
```

I merged this null check (in the `else ""` form) with the decision into one if, so when the input is ended without a line being read, it also prints 0. Also, any string sorting less than "0" lexicographically prints 0, and any string lexicographically > "0" will produce the 1-loop.

The `0<1` is used instead of `true` because it is shorter.

Here is a functional approach, unfortunately it can't compete (107 bytes after whitespace removal) due to the length of `parseInteger`:

```
shared void run() {
    value i = parseInteger(process.readLine() else "") else 0;
    (1:i).cycled.follow(i).each(print);
}
```

It cycles a range starting at 1 of length i (i.e. either {} or {1}), resulting in {} or {1,1,1,1,...}, prepends i (which results in {0} or {1,1,1,1,1,1,...}), and prints each element.

---

A different functional approach without variables and parsing is this one (88 bytes, shrinked version at the top):

```
shared void run() =>
        ("0" < (process.readLine() else "") then
    { 1 }.cycled else { 0 }).each(print);
```

This does the case distinction in an expression, using the `then` and `else` operators to produce either the {1,1,1,...} stream or the {0} singleton, and then calls `print(...)`  on each element of that stream.

Answer (score 0):

### C#, <s>120</s> 98 bytes

```cs
using c=System.Console;class o{static void Main(){if(c.Read()=='1')for(;;c.Write(1));c.Write(0);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```cs
using c=System.Console;
class o
{
    static void Main()
    {
        if(c.Read()=='1')
            for(;;c.Write(1));
        c.Write(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2-byte gain: `int a=c.Read();do c.Write(a-48);while(a>48);`

Comment: 95 bytes based on @LegionMammal978 answer `using c=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){int a=c.Read()-48;do c.Write(a);while(a>0);}}`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 33 <s>37</s> <s>39</s> <s>29</s> bytes

Pretty straight forward:

```
for($f=fgetc(STDIN);$f&print$f;);
```

Runs from command line:

```
php truth.php 1
```

---

**Edits**

- *Added* **10 bytes** as the program *must* take input from STDIN if possible. Thanks to [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) for pointing it out. :)
- *Saved* **2 bytes** by using `if` and `for` instead of `while`. Thanks to [BLackhole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11713/blackhole)
- *Saved* **2 bytes** by placing everything into the `for`-loop. Thanks to [fschmengler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43220/fschmengler).
- *Saved* **2 bytes** by rewriting the 2nd expression of the `for`-loop.

Comment: Actually it's 39 because you have to add either `<?` or the `-r` flag

Comment: But you can save one byte more with this: `<?for($f=fgetc(STDIN);(print$f)&$f;);` - print is like echo but has a return value (always 1)

Comment: @fschmengler Thanks for your feedback. I made it even 2 bytes shorter, by switching `(print$f)&$f` to `$f&print$f`. There is a general discussion about the byte count here: [Is the PHP opening tag mandatory in byte count?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7098/41859).

Answer (score 0):

### Swift, 187 bytes

```
import Foundation
let i = Int("\(String(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.characters.first!)")!
print(i)
while i>0{print(i)}
```

Sadly this has to read from stdin if it can :( Would be so much smaller if I could just declare it inside...

Comment: Can you not remove the spaces around `=`, after `:`, and after `,`?

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, <s>62</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

Golfed:

```
i=prompt();do{alert(i)}while(i)
```

Ungolfed:

```
input=prompt();
do {
    alert(i);
} while(i);
```

-1 byte thanks to [JimmyJazzx's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62947/46603)
-2 bytes and bug fix thanks to [kamoroso94's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/62934?noredirect=1#comment354803_62934)

Comment: You can golf this even more to something like this: `i=prompt();for(;i==1;)alert(i);alert(i)` (39 bytes). Also to read from the user use `prompt()` not alert()`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere thanks for catching that typo! Just fixed it.

Comment: @Martin Büttner♦ Thanks for the formatting fixes!

Comment: This does the opposite of what it's supposed to.  You need to loop on 1, not 0.  Get rid of `<1` and save two bytes to fix your bug.

Comment: Finally got 50 rep, `for(i=prompt();alert(i)|i;);` (28 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

### x86 (Linux / NASM syntax), 86 bytes

```
mov dx,1              ; 3rd argument to read(): length of buffer
mov ecx,esp           ; 2nd argument to read(): the buffer
                      ; 1st argument to read(): the FD is already 0
mov ax,3              ; read system call number
int 128               ; invoke syscall, returns eax=1 == num of read bytes
l:mov ax,4            ; start of loop, eax=syscall number of write()
int 128               ; invoke syscall, returns eax=1 == num of written bytes
cmp byte[esp],49      ; compare buffer against '1'
jz l                  ; loop of it's the same
int 128               ; invoke syscall otherwise (syscall 1 == exit)
```

Compile with `nasm -f elf h.asm && ld -o h h.o -m elf_i386` and ignore all warnings. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Scala, 46 bytes

```
if(readInt==0)print(0)else while(2>1)print(1)
```

Kinda uninteresting and obvious, but there we go

Comment: `==0` can be replaced with `<1`

Comment: `val k=readInt;do{print(k)}while(k>0)`

Answer (score 0):

## Atari Basic, 47 bytes

If I remember the syntax correctly, it will be something like this:

```
1 input a$
2 IF a$="0" THEN end
3 ? a$
4 goto 3
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you need some spaces? (`"0" THEN`, `? a$`)

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I'm not sure, i produced this snippet from memory, i did't use atari basic for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

### [Java](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Java), <strike>90</strike> 97 bytes

```
class T{public static void main(String[]a){while(a[0].equals("1"))System.out.println(1);}}
```

I'm not sure if this counts because it takes 1 or 0 as an argument rather than STDIN. It's been emotional, either way.

Edit:
The above does not print zero, the below does:

```
class T{public static void main(String[]a){do System.out.println(a[0]);while(a[0].equals("1"));}}
```

Comment: You can save two characters by using `print` instead of `println`. (There was no requirement saying each 1 must be on a new line). Also, the command line can be added easily as `while(a[0].equals(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine())`.  However, I don't think this meets the requirement, since it doesn't print 0.

Comment: Fixed to print zero in 97 bytes. I had to use println because print must just be appending to the string so never actually prints a line for me.

Comment: "print must just be appending to the string" .. .what?  `print` and `println` do exactly the same thing, except that `println` prints the text plus the current OS's line delimiter.  See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Xynariz You should only read the input once

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Um ... how is that even relevant to what I said?

Comment: @Xynariz I was talking to the scanner part of your first comment

Comment: @Xynariz I was running in Eclipse and print didn't work as you would expect, hence println (I should maybe start running the files from command line)

Comment: @ESP It should still work, I think there's something weird going on.

Comment: Program args are **not** STDIN!

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, <s>46 bytes</s> 34 bytes

```
x=input() 
print x
while x:print x
```

Basically, it takes in the input, when 1, prints forever (while loop), but if it isn't 1 (when it is zero) it prints and then exits.

This is my first answer! Yay!

Comment: Duplicate of [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62760/39328).

Comment: @lirtosiast Duplicates are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 24 <s>25 27</s> bytes

```
<?=do{echo$i;}while($i); // Also 24b
<?=$i;for(;$i&1;)echo$i; // 24b, added PHP's short echo, actually made it less

echo$i;for(;$i&1;)echo$i; // 25b
echo$i;while($i&1)echo$i; // 25b, based on 0/1 as truthy/falsy

for(;$i&1;){echo$i;}echo$i; //27b
```

This works by setting `register_globals=on` (which you shouldn't) and that going to the page with `?i=1` or `?i=0` in the url.

The logic is that the first echo will always output the input, and if it's *one* it'll loop until something gives in (because of `&` returning 1 (=truthy) for 1).

Comment: Does `register_globals` work with `STDIN`?

Comment: I went for " or an acceptable alternative". I figured it's about the technique, not forcebly use `STDIN`. This is one of the very few 'keep the code shorter' tricks PHP can use, especially compared to the other languages :)

Comment: I get 21 bytes with `do{echo$i;}while($i);`

Comment: But not with the `<?=` in front of it. Added it nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

### [DStack](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DStack), 7 bytes

```
04KKCKT
```

I invented the language after the challenge began, but before I see it.

Comment: Because it's impossible to prove when somebody saw a challenge, claiming that you didn't see a challenge before you created a language normally doesn't make it eligible. However, since this is a catalog challenges, all languages are welcome, even those created after the challenge, so long as they meet our [criteria for being a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/26997). Just something to keep in mind for the future :) Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Mego I already know that, I wrote that just to mention something (besides I had to write more because the answer was too short). But still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### VB.NET, 106 Bytes

```
Imports c=System.Console
Module m
Sub Main
i=c.readline
1:c.Write(i)
if i=1 then goto 1
end sub
end module
```

Straightforward, using goto instead of a loop. Compiles with `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict Off`, and `Option Infer On`

Answer (score 0):

### STATA, 31 bytes

```
di _r(a)
m
do{$a
}while($a)
end
```

First, get input from the user and store it in global variable a. Then switch to Mata for better commands. Print the value of a and then if it is truthy (i.e. 1), go to the start of the loop. If the `end` keyword is omitted, `unexpected end of file (end statement missing)` is output to standard error. I'm not sure if that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift, <s>55 bytes</s>, <s>54 bytes</s>, 53 bytes

```
if readLine()=="1"{while 1>0{print(1)}}else{print(0)}
```

I tried to use ternary for a while but couldn't get it compiling. Maybe someone else will or it is just impossible. I'm open for tips or advice :)

Comment: instead of `while(true)` can you do `while(1)` or `while(1>0)`?

Comment: @Cyoce `error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'Bool'`

Comment: @Simon You can shave off one byte by removing the parentheses after `while`. They serve no purpose in Swift.

Comment: One byte shorter using ternary: `readLine()=="1" ? {while 1>0{print(1)}} : {print(0)}`

Comment: @idrougge 'Expression resolves to an unused function'

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid of me. The functions are never called that way.

Answer (score 0):

## [Staq](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Staq), 5 chars

```
'[:]:
```

Explanation

```
'         input number, put it on top of the active stack
 [        jump to corresponding ] if the top stack value = 0 or nonexistent
  :       output top stack value as number
   ]      jump back to corresponding [ if top stack value >0
    :     output top stack value as number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Cardinal](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 8 chars

```
%:> J.jN
```

Explanation

```
%                     create pointer
 :                    enter number, put it on top of stack
  >                   redirect pointer to the right
                      NOP
    J                 skip next instruction if top stack value is > 0
     .                output number to STDOUT
      j               skip next instruction if top stack value is = 0
       N              reflect pointer to the left
```

The original interpreter, written by [Madk](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Madk), is buggy, and some instructions are missing. I fixed the errors and recompiled the interpreter.

You can clone the fixed interpreter and readme from [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/Cardinal).

Comment: Does it use anything implemented after the question was asked? I think so. Sadly I think this is noncompeting.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Cardinal is from 2010. Madk’s original interpreter (in BlitzMax) contains bugs that break the use of Cardinal, and he forgot to implement one or two commands that exist in his language spec. I fixed these errors and recompiled the fixed source in BlitzMax. Now everything works according to his specification.
This is a catalog, the date of implementation does not matter.

I uploaded my fix on GitHub yesterday, so everyone can enjoy it. The language is 5 years old; I fixed the errors around June 2015, as you can see e.g. [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52371/43477)

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse16](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16), 10 bytes

```
?0+[1!4\]0
```

Asks for input, then coerces it to an int and tests its truthiness. Then, if it's truthy, `1` is printed and the execution jumps to the 4th byte, where `1` is printed again, and so on forever (until the stack overflows), otherwise, `0` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pike](http://pike.lysator.liu.se), 94 bytes

Looks like C, but isn't C. Is interpreted. Is fast.

```
int main(){int x=(int)Stdio.stdin->gets();if(x!=0){for(;;){write("1");}}write("0");return 0;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int main() {
  int x = (int)Stdio.stdin -> gets();
  if (x != 0) {
    for(;;) {
      write("1");
    }
  }
  write("0");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I always want to pronounce `Stdio` as `Studio` :) Can you not write an integer to output?

Comment: @ETHproductions before I actually *learned* C, I always assumed `stdio.h` was some sorta studio something because of Visual Studio... I dunno. To write a number to `stdout` as far as I can tell you need to use `write("%d", x);` because `write` wants a `string` or `array(char)` argument, which is even longer

Answer (score 0):

### [Boo](http://boo-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```
def f(x):
 print x;while x:print x
```

Boo is a language inspired by Python and implemented in .NET. Its syntax is very similar to Python 2's.

Answer (score 0):

## [AnnieFlow](http://esolangs.org/wiki/AnnieFlow), 6 bytes

```
010[!"
```

Here is the decompressed and more readable program:

```
010101101100000110111111
```

Breakdown:

```
010          there are two characters, 0 and 1
1            input is accepted, first symbol popped will be whatever it is
011          there are two stacks, 0 for output, 1 for input
011          1 push occurs when 0 is popped from 1
00           that push is symbol 0 on stack 0 (output 0)
0            pop from the output (halt) when 0 is popped from 1
0011         2 pushes occur when 1 is popped from 1
01           the first push is symbol 1 on stack 0
11           the second push is symbol 1 on stack 1 (replaces the symbol we popped)
1            pop from stack 1, which we just put 1 on, so we loop forever, outputting 1
11           loop forever doing nothing if the input is empty, won't matter
```

Note: under some interpretations of the language, the trailing 1s can be omitted, and the advanced interpreter does this automatically, also added 0 to the end if there are any trailing 1s. The actual decompression is

```
01010110110000011
```

Comment: With an interpreter to use the whole 8 bits/byte for golfing purposes, this could be an interesting golfing language.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 16 bytes

```
qi1={"1o_~"_~}&0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 7 bytes.

```
izwp,1}
```

How it works:

```
i      # Get command line input.
z      # Skip the next instruction if the top of the stack is 0.
wp,1}  # While 1 is truthy, print the stack.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ForceLang](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang), 52 bytes

```
set a io.readln()
label l
io.write a
if a="1"
goto l
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), 12 bytes

This is about the shortest I can do at the moment.

```
*;R?[   X!@J
```

[Try it online](http://fission.tryitonline.net/#code=KjtSP1sgICBYIUBK&input=MA)

```
  R           # Create a atom heading right
   ?          # Set atom mass to input char 
    [         # Set direction right
        X     # Clone atom and sending one back
         !    # Print the character
          @   # Swap mass and energy on atom
           J  # Jump (48 for 0, 49 for 1)
*             # Kill program.  Landing spot for 0
 ;            # Kill atom.  Landing spot for 1
```

The length of this program is quite dependent on the landing spots for the `J`ump command.  There is also a requirement for a bit of space between the `[` direction setter and the `X` linear cloner. Otherwise an extra 0 will get printed.  The input must be either 0 or 1 for this to work.  The input is not validated.

Originally I was going to put up a 18 byte program which is more forgiving on invalid inputs.

```
R?@YI@0'L
O0'&[X'1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>33</s> 31 chars

```
while(alert(x=x||+prompt()),x);
```

Comment: I'm getting "ReferenceError: x is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
(if (= 1(read))(loop (print 1)))
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62926/45941).

Comment: Hmmm ... Are you printing the Zero?

Answer (score 0):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d/), 7 bytes

Turtlèd cannot output without halting, so the truth machine writes down infinite ones, like a turing machine's implementation might, onto the grid if input is 1.

```
!.{1r.}
```

Explanation:

```
!                  input into string variable

 .                 write current char of string var (by default the first char)
                   for a single char input, this will be the entire input

  {1  }            while the current char is 1
                   this loop is never run if input is zero, but if it is one, it will run
                   forever, as the last action of the loop writes 1 to the current cell

    r              move right, so that we constantly move right to write ones to infinite
                   cells

     .             write current char of string var (still by default the first char)
                   this is 1 if the loop was run at all. because the loop runs while the
                   current cell is one, this will cause the loop to rerun every time.

       [implicit]  output grid at end of program, program will only end if input isn't 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [LI](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/LI/blob/master/Interpreter.py), 4 bytes

```
?iRP
```

Explanation:

```
?i       if input is truthy (1):
  RP      Recurse the program with the printed (implied) input
         Else (0 is the only falsy value in LI) return (implied) input, 
              which is implicitly printed.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 7 bytes

```
iAo7ox
```

ABCR is a stack-based programming language that allows a few simple operations on any of its three stacks and a single register.

Explanation:

```
i        Numerical input.  Places result in register.
 A       Queue register value to queue a.
  o      Output peek(a) as a number.
   7     while(register){
    o      output peek(a) again
     x   }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dip, 6 bytes

```
?_1p?0
```

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 19.</sup>

Comment: Perhaps you should provide an explanation rather than a space filler...

Answer (score 0):

## [Doxical](https://github.com/DerpfacePython/Doxical/tree/master), 11 bytes

```
[^]A{AdA}dA
```

First answer in Doxical!

Doxical is my new language, which is designed to be difficult to program in, and is grid-based. Also, there aren't any newlines in Doxical code, so every Doxical program is a one-liner.

Explanation (note that there are no comments in Doxical, this is just for clarification):

```
[^]         # Asks for user input, if input = 1, puts 1 into the Value,
            # If 0, puts 0 into the Value
   A        # Declares variable A as the Value
    {A  }   # While A > 0:
      dA    # Output A in decimal (1 forever)
         dA # Outside the while loop, output A in decimal (0 once)
```

*Yes, "Value" is meant to be capitalised, see docs for more details.*

Answer (score 0):

## [BrainInt](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainInt), 5 bytes

```
&^[!]
```

Explanation:

```
&     # Take user input, and store in current cell
 ^    # Boolean-ate current cell (nonzero -> 1, 0 -> 0)
  [ ] # Loop (while cell != 0)
   !  # Print current cell as integer
```

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL, 22 bytes

```
s:print @ if @>0goto s
```

requires a variable with the name `@`, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @ BIT = 0

s:print @ if @>0goto s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 10 bytes

```
[:out]loop
```

Assumes input is on TOS. [Try it here!](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked/stacked.html)

Loops `[:out]` while TOS is truthy, repeating at least once. Surround with `[]` for a proper function.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 40

```
gets stdin r
puts $r
while \$r {puts $r}
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRHZ5MktOSGdkUWs)

Answer (score 0):

### [Deadfish i](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish_i), 16 bytes

```
0<+I]
1<.
2<+.[2
```

As this language does not support input, you must replace `I` with either an empty string (=0) or `+` (=1). The program works on my interpreter, which may or may not work like the author of the language intended.

I'm not sure how to score this program. Currently the byte count is for 1-variant.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 33 bytes

```
pull n
do while n
  say n
  end
say n
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES5), 40 bytes

```js
function(x){x?while(1)alert(1):alert(0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 7 bytes

```
+?
Dx,O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bnsulQsf/////hgA)

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore but here is a [9 byte](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bniufK7xCJ/////8GAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Decimal](//git.io/Decimal), 32 bytes

```
81D301110D412D590D5111D91D30191D
```

Pretty simple. Explanation:

```
81D   ; builtin to read INT to stack
301   ; print
110D  ; push INT 0
412D  ; compare for equality, pop values used, push result
5     ; if truthy
90D   ;  exit
5     ; endif
111D  ; push INT 1
91D   ; declare jump 1
301   ; print
91D   ; exit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNzsxNzPn/38LQxdjA0NDQwMXE0MjF1NLAxRTIc7EECwPJ//8Nvubl6yYnJmekAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Noether, 5 bytes

```
0(IP)
```

This works very simply:

```
0 - Push 0 to stack
( - Pop value of stack and loop until top of stack equals popped value
I - Push user input to stack
P - Print top of stack
) - End loop
```

Unless you want your browser to freeze, I would advise against testing this online at https://beta-decay.github.io/noether

Answer (score 0):

## [ArcPlus](https://gunnerwolf.github.io/arcplus/index.html), 22 bytes

```
(: n (,))(@ (p n) (p n
```

#### Verbose version:

```
(set n (input))
(while (print n) (print n))
```

Comment: Link to language is dead

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 126 bytes

```java
public static void main(String[]a){int n=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();while(n==1)System.out.print(n);System.out.print(n);}
```

**Ungolfed** (+ comments with explanation)

```java
public static void main(String[]a){
    int n=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//Create the scanner and get the next integer input
    while(n==1)System.out.print(n);//if n == 1, print 1
    //else exit. If there is nothing that happens the java program automatically exits
    System.out.print(n);//But first print out 0
}
```

The reason behind using a scanner is me not being able to get the desired behaviour using `System.in.read()`. Typing 1 exited the program as if it was something else being typed. `System.in.read()` returns an int as 0-255 representing the byte it received, meaning 1 != 1 with that method.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lean Mean Bean Machine](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/lmbm), 18 bytes

```
 O
 i
 ?
 _
u $
  ~
```

### Explanation:

```
 O    - Spawns a marble at program start
 i    - Fetch input and assign to marble's value
 ?    - If marble's value is truthy, spin right, else spin left
 _    - Move in direction of spin
u $   - u terminates marble and prints value, $ prints value
  ~   - Trampoline, move marble to top of field on same column
```

Yep, Mayube's at it again making another language that'll probably be abandoned in a week. This one's not at all golfy though, and inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128851/a-lean-mean-bean-machine)

Comment: 2D languages generally aren't golfy. However, they're interesting to program *in.*

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
$!7{%0&}U3D1R3L1F3B1U1D3(%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9fRdG8WtVArTbU2MUwyNjH0M3YyTDU0MVYQ9VQ8/9/AwA) (May not work for a little while after posting due to TIO's version) Explanation:

```
$                             read integer as input
 !7{...}                      if falsy
    %0                         print 0th face
      &                        exit
        U3D1R3L1F3B1U1D3      quickest way to get 1 onto a face
                        (..)  forever
                         %1    print the first face
```

Comment: `L1D1L3` gets 1 onto face 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
a=bool(input())
print int(a)
while a: print int(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2KT8/RyMzr6C0RENTk6ugKDOvRAGINRI1ucozMnNSFRKtFJBF//8HAA)

Comment: You don't need to cast datatypes.
[33 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRCGRqzwjMydVIdEKyv//3xAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Assembly (as, x64, Linux)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html), 128 bytes

```
.data
i:.byte 0
.text
mov $3,%eax
mov $0,%ebx
mov $i,%ecx
mov $1,%edx
int $128
l:mov $4,%eax
mov $1,%ebx
int $128
cmp $49,i
je l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcsxDoQgEIXhfk5BsXYuEbVwvc2gU2BATZhs4PQ4UWPsvry8H2OkYH3@YixFz8gIbtQ2M6kGNFNiCNtffbq6IkyXG7G97cTTbSOeE7iVxe0Afjzn/pWaK30uU9jl8KsdLKR8KQYO)

Explanation

```
.data
i:.byte 0       ;Declare variable i with type byte

.text
mov $3,%eax
mov $0,%ebx
mov $i,%ecx
mov $1,%edx
int $128        ;Make system call read(eax=3) from stdin(ebx=0) with an address(ecx) and length in bytes(edx)

l:mov $4,%eax   ;Declare section/label l
mov $1,%ebx
int $128        ;make system call write(eax=4) to stdout(ebx=1). There is no need to reassign ecx or edx
cmp $49,i       ;compare the value at the address i to 49(ascii value of "1")
je l            ;jump to label l if equal
```

Answer (score 0):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 141 bytes

```
PLEASE WRITE IN .1
DO (1020) NEXT
DO (1) NEXT
DO COME FROM (3)
(3)DO READ OUT #1
(2)PLEASE RESUME .1
(1)DO (2) NEXT
DO READ OUT #0
DO GIVE UP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2FUhPMgzxFXB009Bz5DLxV9Bw9DAyEBTwc81IgTCRbCd/X1dFdyC/H0VNIw1uYAYKBbk6uii4B8aoqBsyKVhpAk1M8g1OBSoFmgiUD/IFCOEKQgdBiCuu2eYq0JowP///n6uCgA)

Answer (score 0):

## CMD, 30 bytes

```
:a
echo %1
if %1==1 (goto a)
```

Pretty straight-forward

Answer (score 0):

### [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 103 bytes

```
interface J{static void main(String[]a){int n=Integer.decode(a[0]);do System.out.print(n);while(n>0);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoIwEADQX@nYDjbdG911ZSQMl/bEQ7kj5cAYwrfX7u9NsMNFFuQpv2slVixPSGgex6qglMwulM0MxLbTQjz2A7ijOcPXe9MjFp8xSUYLfRhczGK636o4e9nUL62oZRe/L/qg5Vtw8TxrreEP)

ungolfed (although Java doesn't need it that much):

```
interface J{
    static void main(String[]a){
        int n=Integer.decode(a[0]);
        do System.out.print(n);
        while(n>0);
    }
}
```

Using Interface, as since Java 8 interfaces can have function bodies. Because they are always public we are saving some chars. The question states

> take input from STDIN or an acceptable alternative

and for me the run arguments are an acceptable alternative.

Note that `Integer.decode()` throws a `NumberFormatException`, but input will always only be 0 or 1.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing But the question states "The truth-machine must be a full program that follows these rules:", so a function isn't sufficent, right? There already is a 48 byte Java answer which is only a function. I saw one Java answer which is a full program, but it had 120 bytes.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing but thanks for the welcome! But I'm not familiar with any golfing language and most of my knowledge lies in Java, which also is not that much... So I don't think you'll see that much of me ;)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I know that already, I watched quite some challenges :P But of course, a 3 byte Jelly or something else solution is more liked than a 100 byte Java solution :P
But lets see if I'll manage something nice some day ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bitwise](//github.com/aaronryank/bitwise), <s>52</s> <s>46</s> 38 bytes

<sup>Oh, that's right, I made the interpreter not care about the return value for I/O. It was definitely not for code golf.</sup>

```
IN 1 &1
OUT 1 &1
XOR 1 &48 2
JMP &-3 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osKc8sTv3/39NPwVBBzZDLPzQEwojwDwIxTCwUjLi8fAMU1HSNFYz@/zcEAA)

Translated to C (labels added instead of literal jumps for clarity):

```
IN 1 &1        mem[1] = getchar();
LABEL &1       label_1:
OUT 1 &1         putchar(mem[1]);
XOR 1 &48 2      mem[2] = (mem[1] ^ 48);   // ^ is equivalent to !=
JMP @1 2       if (mem[2]) goto label_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 34 bytes

```
> Input
>> Output 1
>> DoWhile 1 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/99OwTOvoLSEy85Owb@0BMhSMASxXfLDMzJzUhUMFYz@/zcAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
`Đƥłŕ
```

Explanation:

```
`  ł     (Do ... while top of stack is true)
 Đ       Duplicate top of stack
  ƥ      Print top of stack
    ŕ    Pop top of stack and discard
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f8/4ciEY0uPNh2d@v@/AQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp), 28 bytes

```
;;;;;;;;~*~-(;~;;;;;;~)~p(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K84o@P/fGgrqtOp0NazroBzNugKNAs3//w0A)

```
;;;;;;;;~*~-(;~;;;;;;~)~p(p)
;;;;;;;;                      set acc0 = 8
        ~*~                   set acc1 = input
           -(;        )       while(acc0--)
              ~;;;;;;~            acc1 -= 6
                              this leaves us with a `0` or `1` values for character input
                       ~p     print acc1
                         ( )  while(acc1)
                          p       print acc1
```

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
^'0-[$.$]$#
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Draw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155408/65965), 21 bytes

```
start 0 1 start start
```

This is the version of the program where 1 is input. To change the input to 0, replace the 1 with a 0. The program where the 1 is there will produce an infinite line of marked squares towards y=+∞ starting at x=0, y=1; if the 1 was replaced, there will be only one marked square, at x=0, y=0.

Answer (score 0):

### [Aheui](//esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), 33 bytes

```
방챵뱍벅나명희멍터벅벅
```

You can test it with [jsaheui](http://aheui.github.io/jsaheui/jsaheui_en.html), or [rpaheui](https://github.com/aheui/rpaheui).

#### How does it works?

```
// When input is 0
방챵뱍벅나명희멍터벅벅
ⓐⓑ　　　　ⓖⓕⓔⓓⓒ

// When input is 1
방챵뱍벅나명희멍터벅벅
ⓐⓑⓓⓒⓔⓕ
　　　ⓖ
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin Script](https://kotlinlang.org/), 41 bytes

```
readLine().let{while(it=="1")print("1")}
```

Pretty Printed:

```
readLine()
    .let{
        while(it=="1")
            print("1")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 36 bytes

Another [basic](/questions/tagged/basic) answer that takes input as integer, `n` and outputs to the console.

```vb
Input""n
If n Then Do?1Loop Else?0Fi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESSmPyzNNIU8hJCM1T8El397QJz@/QME1pzjV3sAt8/9/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Quarterstaff](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Quarterstaff), 12

```
49-?{49!}49!
```

### explanation

(value = 0 to start)

`49` - add 49 to value

`-` - invert value (value = -49 now)

`?` - take a character of input (49 for "1", 48 for "0"), and add it to the value (value = 0 or -1 now)

`{` - begin while not loop. will only be entered if input is 1 or starts with 1 (it should only start with 1 if it is 1).

`49` - add 49 to value. value is now 49

`!` - print value, set value to 0.

`}` - end while not loop.

`49` - add 49 to value (which was -1). value is now 48

`!` - print value, set value to 0 (not relevant to the program, but all ! do this)

it looks like it could be golfed by assigning 49 to something, but it would take 2 more bytes to assign it, then 2 more bytes to use it in the first part, then only byte saving of 2 for the other two occurences of 49

### Previous version of Quarterstaff, 11

I removed %, so this isn't valid in the new version

```
?1%{49!}47!
```

`?` - input a character (49 for "1", 48 for "0") add to value

`1` - add 1  (value is 50 or 49 now)

`%` - value = value %2 (0 if "1" was inputted, 1 if "0" was inputted)

`{` - begin while not value loop

`49` - add 49 to value

`!` - print value, value = 0

`}` - end while not value loop

`47` - add 47 to value

`!` - print value, value = 0

Answer (score 0):

## [QUARK](https://github.com/moonheart08/quark-interp), 11 bytes

This is 6.75 bytes in QUARK's encoding, but that's not finished yet (no encoder), so I'll score this in UTF8 until then.

```
i‶{p}⟲
```

As QUARK became capable of doing a truth machine (implementation wise) less than a minute ago (from when I started writing this answer), it obviously needs an explanation, so here you go:

```
i Get input from the user (as a number)
 ‶ Pin the input to the stack (Pinning is QUARK's way of avoiding a million and one dupes, by simply making the value undeletable until you run the pin command on it again.)
  { Begin a block
   p Print a value off the stack. Because the input is pinned, it's not consumed.
    } End the block, and push it to the stack (when the program reaches this point)
     ⟲ Execute the block. If the top of the stack is not after the first execute 0, execute the block until it is. As the input is pinned, it will always be either 0 or 1. So the block either executes once, or infinitely.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 9 bytes

```
i0-8_Ii_I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P8/00DXIt4zM97z/3@Df/kFJZn5ecX/dTMB) Requires the `-i` interpreter flag.

The provided Momema interpreter has a `-i` flag which enables interactive mode. In interactive mode, expressions can have *holes*, which evaluate to a value read from STDIN. Normally, this would just be equivalent to `*-8`, but it also allows holes to be named with a string of capital letters. When a named hole is evaluated, its value is cached, and when a hole with the same name is evaluated again it is reused. This is intended to be for debugging purposes, but it also means that we can refer to input without having to assign it.

### Explanation:

```
                                                 #  i = input num
i   0   #  label i0: jump past label i0 (no-op)  #  do {
-8  _I  #            output num _I               #    print num i
i   _I  #  label i1: jump past label i(_I)       #  } while i
```

Answer (score 0):

## [2DFuck](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/2DFuck), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.[!..!..!...!.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M0pJK03O/v9fRw8VRivq6UEQEMf@/28IAA)

Explanation:

```
,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,. Read and print a byte, accumulator is last bit = 0 or 1
[!..!..!...!.]   While the accumulator is 1, print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charm](https://github.com/Aearnus/charm), 42 bytes

```
getline " 1 " eq put [ dup ] [ put ] while
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILMr9/z89tSQnMy9VQUnBEIhTCxUKSksUohVSSgsUYoE0iBerUJ6RmZP6/78hAA)

You strangely can't cast to an integer in Charm, so I had to check for equality with `1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 10 bytes

```
IsO@
~>1O~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/9@z2N@Bq87O0L/u/38DAA)

Answer (score 0):

### ABAP, 61 bytes

Hardcoded VALUE 1 for variable i, replace with 0 to not trigger the infinite loop.

```
DATA x TYPE I VALUE 1.
WHILE i=1.
WRITE i.
ENDWHILE.
WRITE i.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)](http://www.nasm.us/), 119 bytes

```
mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,i
mov edx,1
int 80h
l:mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
int 80h
cmp byte [i],49
je l
section .data
i:db 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RctBCoMwEEDR/ZxiDjAtEV20XqW4mCQDnZLEQoLE00dQ1N2Dz@ecJdqwPhLn2FqcFxSu1MMuW8kccpX0kK/UgaaCL/OFMJ7HcB13dfGPdi2CH51oeMNPMEAWV3RO@PRcGHT0Fk1r3QY)

I was surprised that, while there is a 128 byte submission in [as](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137866/44998), there isn't a nasm submission, despite it being shorter!

Literally a port of the as submission into nasm.

Answer (score 0):

## [bitch](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitch), 5 bytes

This infinitely outputs 1 for an input of 1 and outputs 0 once for an input of 0.

```
\>/;<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSc74/z/GTt/a5v9/AwA)

---

#### Explanation

```
\         Input of an integer (restricted by challenge to 0 or 1)
 >        Loop marker #1
  /       Output
   ;<     If not equal to 0, jump to loop marker #1
          (Implicit end of program)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 54 bytes

```fs
let x=stdin.Read()
while x=49 do printfn"1"
printfn"0"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RKHCtrgkJTNPLyg1MUVDk6s8IzMnFShoYqmQkq9QUJSZV5KWp2SoxAVjGij9/28AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, PC DOS, 10 bytes

```
00000000: a082 00cd 293c 3174 fac3                 ....)<1t..
```

**Listing**

```
A0 0082     MOV  AL, DS:[82H]       ; AL = first char from command line 
        DISPLAY: 
CD 29       INT  29H                ; DOS fast write AL to console 
3C 31       CMP  AL, '1'            ; was input a '1'? 
74 FA       JE   DISPLAY            ; if so, loop "forever" 
C3          RET
```

**Sample output**

A standalone DOS .COM program.

```
A>TRUTH.COM 0
0

A>TRUTH.COM 1
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111
(ended because Ctrl-Break was hit)
```

Note: shouldn't ever crash or run out of memory since no memory is used. More likely it'll just burn a permanent screen full of 1's onto your IBM 5151 monochrome CRT monitor (so in a sense it will run forever).

Answer (score 0):

### [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 38 bytes

```lua
x=io.read()repeat print(x)until x~='1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/wjYzX68oNTFFQ7MotSA1sUShoCgzr0SjQrM0ryQzR6GizlbdUP3/fyMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), 139 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 0
1 2 1 1 3 0 0
1 3 1 1 4 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
0 5 0 1 6 0 0
0 6 0 1 7 0 0
0 7 0 1 8 1 1
1 7 1 0 8 1 0
0 8 0 1 7 1 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc25DQAgDAPAnikYgR/moadDYvwQW1YK64hR7tnvmaWIyT6eITFzLBQSmypVqqnZ2OxSp4Y0qClNauF3wCtuQNgtNV1mHw)

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 52 bytes

```
main(i){for(scanf("%d",&i);i;)puts("1");puts("0");}
```

-27 bytes thanks to JoKing
-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SKM4OTEvTUNJNUVJRy1T0zrTWrOgtKRYQ8lQSdMawjIAsmr//zcAAA)
I though I'd try something other than my primary language (Java).

Comment: @JoKing implicit int type? That's good to know.

Comment: You can even use `main(i)`.

Comment: Furthermore, `while(...)` is equivalent to `for(;...;)`, making space for your `scanf` and allowing for the semicolon to be dropped.

Comment: @JonathanFrech thanks. You can probably tell that I don't know C very well :)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
int main(){for(int c=getchar();putchar(c)-48;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJrm4JCUz344rM69EITcxM09Dszotv0gDxE22TU8tSc5ILNLQtC4ohbCSNXVNLKw1rWv//zcAAA)

Answer (score 0):

### VTL-2, 25 bytes

```
1 A=?
2 ?=A
3 #=4-2*A
```

Line numbers always take up two bytes in VTL, hence the byte count discrepancy.

This should work in VTL-1 as well, but I don't have an interpreter to ensure that is the case. I've tested this under a VTL-2 interpreter running on an Altair 8800 simulator, both sourced from [here](http://www.classiccmp.org/cpmarchives/cpm/mirrors/www.schorn.ch/cpm/intro.php). Here's a [PDF manual for VTL-2](http://www.altair680kit.com/manuals/Altair_680-VTL-2%20Manual-05-Beta_1-Searchable.pdf).

VTL was a small (<800 bytes!) and simple language for the Altair 8800 and 680 machines. Its creative use of system variables helped to keep it small. `?` represents both input and output. Note that this truth machine outputs no line breaks, as those *always* need to be manually printed (by printing an empty string, `?=""`). `#` represents line number, and can be used to retrieve the current line number *or* assigned to form a goto. That should be enough to make this truth machine make sense...

```
1 A=?         ) Put input into variable A
2 ?=A         ) Print the contents of variable A
3 #=4-2*A     ) Goto 4-(2*A)... So, (nonexistent) line 4 if input was 0
              ) Or back to line 2 if input was 1. Yes, `)` is the comment character.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aheui](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 28 bytes

```
붕박누망홰
차봇멍보
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9haGV1af//67aV67CV64iE66ed7ZmwCuywqOu0h@upjeuztP//MA)

Additionally, I found bug of TIO with Aheui : Aheui is befunge-like, but initial direction is up-to-down, but TIO's initial direction is right-to-left, so my original code got error.

Answer (score 0):

## [EZLang](https://github.com/dhnam/EZLang), 105 bytes

```
MEM(0)
SET(-1)
MEM(1)
GET()
SET(-1, 1)
JLZ(12)
SET(1, 1)
MEM(1)
PRT()
MEM(0)
JLZ(8)
SET(1, 1)
PRT()
HLT()
```

Self-made esolatic language.

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 4 bytes

```
O[o]
```

### Explanation:

0 input:

```
O    | Get input
  o  | Print it
 [ ] | Loop ends because accumulator is 0
```

1 input:

```
O    | Get input
 [ ] | While the accumulator is 1 (forever)
  o  | Print it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 7 bytes

```
&>:.:_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83OSs8q3uH/fwMA)

`_` is the horizontal `if` in befunge - conveniently, it sends the IP right if the top of the stack is `0` (so it hits `@` to end the program), and left if the top of the stack is nonzero (which puts it in an infinite loop).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70733/59487).

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 6 bytes

```
i:?@:$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/Tyt7BSuX/fwMA)

`?` is a conditional jump command that skips `n` instructions where `n` is a value popped from the top of the stack. If that value is 0, we dump the stack and terminate. If its 1 we skip that instruction and print the value, leaving a copy on the stack, then loop. `i` does nothing if there is no more input to read.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```
do{alert(x=x||prompt())}while(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Unsuspected-hangul](https://github.com/dragonteros/unsuspected-hangeul), 187 bytes

```
ㅀㄱ ㄱㅇㄱ ㅅㅅㅎㄴ ㄳㅎㄴㅎ ㄱㅀㄷ ㄱㅇㄱ ㅁㅈㅎㄴ ㅈㅀㄴ ㄱㅇㄴ ㄴㅇㅎㄴ ㅂㄱㅎㄱ ㄳㅎㄴ ㄱㅇㄴ ㄴ ㄴㅎㄷㅎㄷㅎ ㄱㅀㄷㅎ ㄱㅀㄷ
```

[You can try it here](https://dragonteros.github.io/unsuspected-hangeul/pbhhg.html)

Note that it use pop-up for standard output, and you have to close tap to terminate the program.

### How does it work?

```
ㄹ ㅎㄱ [ㄱㅇㄱ ㅅㅅㅎㄴ ㄱㅅㅎㄴ ㅎ] ㄱㄹㅎㄷ bind(input(), int)
    [def print_and_recursion(x) num -> IO(nil)
    ㄱㅇㄱ ㅁㅈㅎㄴ ㅈㄹㅎㄴ print(str(x))
        [def recursion_part(not_used) nil -> IO(nil)
        (ㄱㅇㄴ ㄴㅇ ㅎㄴ) print_and_recursion(x)
        (ㅂㄱㅎㄱ ㄱㅅㅎㄴ) IO(nil)
        (ㄱㅇㄴ ㄴ ㄴㅎㄷ) ㅎㄷ if(x == 1) then... else...
    ㅎ]
    ㄱㄹㅎㄷ bind(print(str(x)), recursion_part)
ㅎ]
ㄱㄹㅎㄷ bind(bind(input(), int), print_and_recursion)
```

Unsuspected-hangul(평범한 한글) is Korean character-based functional esolang.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 55 bytes

```
Fn.new{|x|
while(x){
System.print(x)
if(x==0)Fn.x()
}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikUFJUWpKhYKvw3y1PLy@1vLqmooarPCMzJ1WjQrOaK7iyuCQ1V6@gKDOvBCjAlZmmUWFra6AJVFyhoclVy1X7H6qkvCizJFUDbJpecmJOjoahpuZ/AA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|      // As usual, new anonymous function x
                // Newline as we are entering statements, not an expression
while(x){       // While the input x is true:
                // (Everything other than false, the null string, and the
                // empty list is true)
System.print(x) // Output x to the console with a newline
if(x==0)Fn.x()  // If the input is 0 then exit the program
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fugue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fugue), 120 bytes

```
00000000: 4d54 6864 0000 0006 0001 0002 0001 4d54  MThd..........MT
00000010: 726b 0000 002b 0090 4040 0290 3e40 0190  rk...+..@@..>@..
00000020: 3a40 0090 4040 0190 4740 0190 4340 0090  :@..@@..G@..C@..
00000030: 4440 0190 3e40 0190 3740 0190 3740 00ff  D@..>@..7@..7@..
00000040: 2f4d 5472 6b00 0000 2f00 9040 4001 9037  /MTrk.../..@@..7
00000050: 4001 903f 4001 9040 4002 903c 4000 9044  @..?@..@@..<@..D
00000060: 4001 903e 4002 9045 4001 9046 4001 904e  @..>@..E@..F@..N
00000070: 4001 9047 4000 ff2f                      @..G@../
```

Since the Fugue compiler does not support voice wrapping, a direct translation of [Martin Ender's Prelude answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62805) turns out to not be the shortest possible solution. This program is equivalent to the Prelude program:

```
 v6(1-)#
?!^ 8- (^!)
```

See [my Hello World answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215708) for more information on how to use the compiler. Finally, here's a valid MIDI version of the program:

```
00000000: 4d54 6864 0000 0006 0001 0002 0001 4d54  MThd..........MT
00000010: 726b 0000 002c 0090 4040 0290 3e40 0190  rk...,..@@..>@..
00000020: 3a40 0090 4040 0190 4740 0190 4340 0090  :@..@@..G@..C@..
00000030: 4440 0190 3e40 0190 3740 0190 3740 00ff  D@..>@..7@..7@..
00000040: 2f00 4d54 726b 0000 0030 0090 4040 0190  /.MTrk...0..@@..
00000050: 3740 0190 3f40 0190 4040 0290 3c40 0090  7@..?@..@@..<@..
00000060: 4440 0190 3e40 0290 4540 0190 4640 0190  D@..>@..E@..F@..
00000070: 4e40 0190 4740 00ff 2f00                 N@..G@../.
```

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, 11 bytes

```
x48S-:n[:n]
```

### Explanation

```
<implicit input> - Take input from STDIN
x                - Clean up the linefeed from STDIN
 48S-            - Remove 48 from the digit's ascii code
     :n          - Output the number
       [:n]      - While non-zero: Output the number
```

### Language Link

**[Github Repo](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

Not a winner, but I like the method.

```python
set(iter(lambda x=input():(print(x),x)[1],'0'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzi1RCOzJLVIIycxNyklUaHCNjOvoLREQ9NKo6AoM69Eo0JTp0Iz2jBWR91AXVPz/38DAA)

Answer (score 0):

#### x86_16 machine code -  20 bytes

```
3E A0 82 00   MOV AL, DS:[82H]
8A D0         MOV DL, AL
          _LOOP:
B4 02         MOV AH, 02H
CD 21         INT 21H
80 FA 31      CMP DL, "1"
74 F7         JZ _LOOP
             
B8 00 4C      MOV AX, 4C00H
CD 21         INT 21H
```

Tested in DOSBox :

**Input `0`**

[image]

**Input `1`**

If input **`1`** gives infinite loop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>18</s></sup> 13 bytes

```
xqqp/1
@qq@qx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v6KwsEDfkMuhsNChsOL/fwMA)

Somehow, there was no existing vim answer for this. I was happy to oblige.

-5 bytes from Aaron Miller.

### Explanation

```
xqqp/1
x      delete the input char 
 qq      start macro q
   p     paste the input
    /1   find 1 (exits if 0 isn't matched)

@qq@qx    
@q       recursively call macro q
  q    end macro q
   @q  call macro q
     x delete last char (never gets executed in the case of 1)
```

Comment: Does this meet the "If that number is 1, print out 1 forever." requirement? Trying it online doesn't produce any output

Comment: vim doesn't show output on tio, sadly. The keystrokes work correctly in the terminal.

Comment: Maybe I can upload a gif.

Comment: @Razetime [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/v/v6KwsEDfkMuhsNChsOL/fwMA "V (vim) – Try It Online") - `/1` will work in this case instead of `:s/1/1`, and if you put `x` before the macro instead of using `Y`, then you can replace the `dk` with another `x`.

Comment: @AaronMiller Great, added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 2 bytes

```
RÃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP9Bh5v/A43@zwgA) Takes input as a character, and outputs in unary using characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pinecone](https://github.com/wmww/Pinecone), 41 bytes

```
n:"".input;n="1"?(tru@print:1)|(print:0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CSASM v2.3.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.3.1), 54 bytes

```
func main:
in ""
conv i32
.lbl a
dup
dup
print
brtrue a
ret
end
```

**Explanation:**

```
func main:
    ; Get the input and convert it to an integer
    in ""
    conv i32

    .lbl a
        ; Duplicate the input twice
        ; Both the "print" and "brtrue" instructions pop a value from the stack
        ;   so this is necessary to keep a 1 on the stack when looping
        dup
        dup
        print

        ; Truthy values are a non-zero integer or a non-null object
        brtrue a
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CASL II](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CASL), 72 bytes.

[Tested here.](https://www.officedaytime.com/dcaslj/)

```
A START
 IN B,1
D OUT B,1
 LAD GR1,48
 XOR GR1,B
 JNZ D
 RET
B DS 1
 END
```

If you are familiar with assembly languages, you would get it well. It uses standard i/o. It uses ASCII-compatible encoding.

Comment: It's stupid that `START` requires a label.

Comment: Also it's buggy because `1` in `IN B,1` and `OUT B,1` is an address rather than a literal; maybe buffer overflow may occur when assembled. However, wherever the assembled code starts from, it seemed that those two macros are assembled using `LAD` command: actually not problem, at least on [this emulator](https://www.officedaytime.com/dcaslj/).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 0 bytes (content) + 13 bytes (filename).

Filename is:

```
._.c.n.w1.o.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5khCckgKhKjUvBazlGq1rqsgK4QgoIhcJKgaOB89d49kyAQeruua2lmfvs5@zEPn4OnX58/25Zl79pOZ69X2C9Qy@o525Zd2rZ7RVrQqb1T0vec3UKv8ClwQqQ6E2MytIJnpOuFguFMxyM/RGfVh8rZmVk1cPg2dtCjE9ojr5fN8pk9Gg4tr0sOta7zonkT10WFwyzNZhPhi8r1V1MQccKH1PFCAScRMWIfuTyPB@pcWJj90ajfPny/rpkFXd9egBffvtdvz34@VL9dXZ1Ur01qNJEgRl8q378@3Jxcfa9/a5Tlt7mATPSG2tksX9UIjUdBfxrP5C@xyN3/kHCGE9cKHRQ8cf7ROITh68jvBmO3H2azltu3AqQ@IkmMqCyIx8JcMiX2lbLZxo@zs@p5zSxzG5jZ6xrBU78XGnyMGF8COPbTCImfCbNMmeUMGCqM3O5hFkL/YrlIyKCe5QaOMJut0rhqLj2dBU4XSYE21d40I4A/75rEFb6jNhPiXMCzELUxwSNIQsVD6ks4obPQR2o1QK2mru63kdRsebm2NHv0nTHKx8q1@@KuqEXliiF2jIahtTw@vwBz9/l8y9M0o1Mx5vG0ec/0UFoQtbFmhKtgSd/EKKWiNkqBe/ubGKUg7aUZS5sY1XdErZ9m3N7E9oHvIY2BZTuF7e5tYpSCcJBe3/YmRim4@JJm3N3EqA4R66Xd1jcxqkPEnLSP@5sYpUVR89OmC5sYpSD9mmbc28RgvxCh0FKMpU2MFsDHtzTj/iZGC@DPezoJ@m8wcMdKL3pnE6MUYhumLRc3MaqDO8N0vPc2MaqDO9206dImVoT0y2kMXFRT2DbwZdIYeC2mMXBmi2FzaYZtK9kuuiRpSt6vWnTKmnJqdKH/Tpl0C@dbpIVbHvubz7WIqLW2W4UW1YAr0PI56Nbpen@XXUPMRFrzdfr2bnXbWiZqGB0XFM6NN2h2DWmG1rxPqKzERQ11tTUdqoekxHzz/lhpg13wADfjIbhQOEbMhaeEJ8ZRPgck7llsHdYz5m6KmsLQDrgAKY5glokCGFW0sdG5BDRmU45BwQdj94Oxq9UWjGtsC0oSh7JviFFs7hgx1bDFcW5UWSBhhYdWzDSA0vKaSH1v57pMW@ivILAkHp92vFiNkyxgG/OcxouzYqk5eFu@/FCZ576Fl6k9N4nHV4hMrQJxmSbJ5ZFdxi2Oz2miif/GrsSeJFn/naCEFkfHSkK0fg@7VsdxTVNoUYFEfCW4OR55/Qc7eOk5fjiUM@KW2mbcLYqJoT3GPKweWxFVWnNGusAtmtCsVZeCSQcLLCGCwqSPYCyUhWNB4WbJPDG4zv8n5pqodXzHeuYTyFsFC@5oNEbeKERDK7Sf@t6jAKzSYrkyJloHU8L4VT5W40mGT3Q@FmH8TzLe4mPggT7kPSj1Rn4SJnDGMEgkGR8NKs0lQn79p1E5PzGl/EPeznv5V5of5S3pU/Vb4/qkcW1K0ic89vte2IODnLMKs1cbqTaBI/pX4Num9OXktN6IIB1y4DhdEvhwdcJ8OO9NPDvsjzx0gWsk@t58Vv7GpG3WDBi2ZXlJP8Ek8p1w4nsoIwPPkvLXkgL4IV1S/l5SmLol4XqNwEyqdIV8i69IdGUCF3dDVY2E@WrJM8FVEvF1o@oSPcVXyt2Hbrgaun3POdSPRL2srjj2NTYgUoOXxD2vNxkqQxDIGoRiaNP8D2Z@4pkrtiv4fOHR@UyAHEL82fWzH6IV02NY@utT33VwBkJKRquRhEkE4Gw2wbdAWxI8XFdulJriEpZFLhjdmMBjuKbreI/hE74hBqukOtxh6wema5AJxjUT1hKEPr5R6rKsUEL@Ffi6hKOaXCyViztkvjTSB@sX@HTN8AM@V6rKnfKTROemkH8oowa0goW6jt0fwp0SFus8Oj58x5NQMKomiBt34APzhRUzuFvcO6hms9WDnRLhzWUAVv1XuC82t3faIuwLd2axqFYT4bj/gAWXYjFahIBUTXO7QKKYBa77Yd@bOHMWccZaPSiWgOdwZ48wKDa@NBtrJj9N/JOgqlosGSx7xgW@y/1cWau9iP4Fvl4LQrAg3K4m6wVyMlBuSFQ3dW5xYPI6hvAPWNkqA1VtmzcsUWxWb3MQ8tDm80F7JfT@0jREFPP@JDlWAysGX5dNs@nNFF8q3FYG2pFFOAOzS14iN@blAeNNZG@WQm9/FDr8vdD7hxtMiruhrrkSLhbzBL1rrpGGQHqGYkHwGrrAjL5C7GALAhqX@F@swi@wdQTissUiUb5NImIsd4ycSdVCDlsHOsmxnMF3Jaj/pPUNko65TRaLBzmXQMWAGSG/BYdBHqpRKKM7x4e7Uf@lH4AagRUKS4p1NDh0jwZbbtndGpT5WONjyNE83mHBM1NvQznAA25jT7aJIC2d60Ek1riS7VyYbT6o/vCeMuODKD794XIFBxN716q@90xn9gRGXQlJSO0VFicWXFYucJawh92KOw4v5vgkjKBweUE/y7Ihy4MDzDZhVrQQ8jj8g2QKA2L8fhlsuV3HdeDtC3mGVki2J2gQWa4fgLhM45bgJ02da5Qp9Em86cvxvD2XDHZSsUc/XI9sxP8xMGEdMhqyZy6A/ga4jGG3iNRGcY1hNsNjeHJX4B3f7ypO2B86ytgeT5SX4N3owmOdrOag@OdHLQqtvgtX1uJKgNm1OSqxqwu/IEkz6/UZdCHLVAu0uFcsbe8WS0iKLNkU9flJo5acGhac9sKn/zv/idYkOuwjQALgwBc4SRJ1uHfBj4CCOD1Y2BoJiqgTaTa1/EeIQX2KksxN0adf@n8B)

### As verbose pseudocode

```
push numeircal integer input
dup
unless empty: printf "%d", $(pop)
while one of
  1. empty
  2. $(pop) != 0
do
  push "1", a character
  unless empty: printf "%c", $(pop)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

## Subleq (8-bit), 15 bytes

```
-1 15   3
15 16   6
15 -1 -48
16  8  -1
15  8   6
```

### Explanation

- `0: -1 15 3` Input character to 15:, goto 3
- `3: 15 16 6` 16: = 16: - 15: (16: = -15), goto 6
- `6: 15 -1 -48` Output 15: (-48 is unused in instruction and used for memory)
- `9: 16 8 -1` 8: = 8: - 16: , if 8: <= 0 exit; exit for all characters "0" and before
- `12: 15 8 6` 8: = 8: - 15: (back to -48), if 8: <= 0 goto 6

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

New method with suggestions from the language's author:

```
I+0P W1O1O0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltc9vIDf4s/Yq1MpZIikpI2p25kURpkpyd8dSxc3bSfLDVmKYom3PUSiUp@9zE/espgH3hUi9p015mLIq7D7DAs1gAq8S9uzj@/iLlcbaaJsOinKaLl/ejpjmSpbe1obh8WiZroDzld7WhMp0LzDSZpTxhWcayBb@jj6Ye/Xj26T3zq9fLjxcsqF7/9vqCHVavx2dv2S/V68Un5lfg49NLA3v26dSAfjp7//ryr1ZhMws/2uxf/l9sPfv6EpYVk/F9lDPHrgRMFNiqVYxG7LCaOzv6jJMcJsmjbwy/D4drGFyGMOgmYLLMRmAN8@b8/JRA@DEmJ/vom2HIxTsBAHnD1ocoWyW2fcUndrNJfsCuXE3Ci9bR@bH1/aTrfWCf/XP/3Ptuw0hrIEAOoJJozkKED5pN0LmM8iKxbPa12Uh5ydJBswGjpN9lzmzFYxgh4Rjey/nSLZb8KpiEXz3XewYdjRTUER6eHg68eoXq0yV7vE/LpFhGcdJswPcssWAcxC1hhsta1@U1v55d5@zr89XEsvsvWjaZ0khnzNLWhqzzomMzoUKN7sHoNYfhbleMgJ2NJCsSc@BZmBPfJ/HvbLbIGV/Nb5O8kPYwKy2m6V1aKq2wOrrju9oj8XSY77Euc6Tl3a7NeqzjdWAJtDS1WZ6Uq5wzFRFCjIJisG7DQ5Sn0W2WKCvAiGzxmORWDOspQ9i3b0wZF9NbTER86diSnnSL62nou7BHoR5esw7PmIxFgPDpamnhljLJaY/B26bB4sQXQpsw47rTqWxqdcSmgTB4oI1ioAQyBHwHy5ZRUbLyPgFlUV4CWG6AoxjFDY1t9EQZaxycncbCp2/TRjcqMsh8DN0yXXAwGyPWm4BpsWKkWC2XSLitokqNmPSb8Qe0G2SjDhXKSw5xDNkKI1daLlj52NFHWgwc4wBmrj5mLDRTBRklO@GqhXajqVGWLWLr0HN9Gx3EYe0EOchXWRblT6aj1f5cGNvzoaMtowWl/IqvSdMSPi4hk8I2T4/evL35be/013PDX1PrbbpVbbCpdq@m993J5Q6NZZKTyohP2T9WkXpFtQ/mEgebSwj/33U0FSdbqCDhw7pwHfNMmTJfcdyggUy4TrkoLJUqKf4hsss0ZjR7u5pdBYcTaYfY5zZlB21AsYRTVc4sgIL/@1k2bam0QwXHRSXrCuBMaAWilIn1a7gh8w/qfqLzGIpj1irzVdKCENTjGJEwPosggeBECwOrVZGAfqLvsuYQHV/eLBYZzNzWGdjpa@XWjxxyft4j08zbDTMztJH/qTZC0JaLLLNMU13muVAg/geT@YbJWITfv/5w5mIpFoEGrydXvud5EE7gCryqtyL9Z/KlZPgYGDFqeIsMwJuLHwF9HoS@quiY4LCo44M@A/E4AMDxyemRw2aQGwcNHdpyPczCcbR0s4RTA2BwpVoiwRmcu11krAtiacLKhvXGSqmVgFI8JC4GUFNSnNR5I54v13aASEonVQpBmtIJLlM8pmV8bznAzEYHhRzFWJ8gY/aVqOzwcsg4lt32/pjhP9xdgfwASLBB2HiXlBk0alabuGwjQ1ihpim3B4Y@ajrLHGsYPGyqsULbkdAm2jI8a9jyYc5X0rinMjNVNryprBV4PfO2mkFJ/JMaK8wNYJBr2N1wuVgm3DIWdlt5i@owWBXORRmC3Q4D7/AXGpeV2xLlfgamT9Ep6I8gIFxsngAOhZnecA1YWm2eBYOsG1KfgecBkLYkE/TQWkQkanBCFpgNQUVj5clv4EnyB/RIeJY2/Nyr7Sl123uYJzaApxubD6tkdV4M@K@dvmzCRByFJss6r8j83jqjntPCDG@rFD8aHdpV17aRbJToJXVe1n6BgmbAbxMGOqGvMNeFPGW3KqiawOSdRFyq3VUgZEUwd0CeXMnCecUChr24VSBpYj9r1LF2m64ovR5CJ6KHvKZetqHM2n/pFGCPBW82UwcpN8xflYXafR0TopESBnW1QZSFIBthwsPQMrZHtKqN@m6L@x6ioalmKpYCsefYXNJhEBtAKBzGVBkqLwN7e6jGUakesqXzuxVNtvqOumxo9Vx6ljJHSL96G9FpRDv2wXV7hZBT7c4WFtaL3xYenA0exL5uY2G@xTWHMKGphAQgw1tUZsLONdygEDTo9UifJIoK0vpGC0bL2ul/9UNiXm0nZv@HQvvbhf5ObNYcEn05jQWmlwNJu2A9ZD1fs0xYoN6Hc9bz4Yz5Jjj4SfQQ0mMNG4YIpXX7asRTlBPRwciTXAc2NQNOSPw31w8ETZIr0IFTgsUSA9@xIb9P8qRTML6ADjXNypSzx@gJeGPTBVz4yuQuyUFmueAJL9MIe3Q4yQv2mLD76CEBoFSE8JLNI76C8Hl6iaPo3S0yDlQQE8UqK/FGTovrhKcgPROjllyjzJTTkDX1qG830tttiIYNayiPLr9RhrXxCbzm0yyZspvK7But5St@E22PsUjlzAiV9Xrq3SZ4Q0Idw/RnnQeHFKxrhQ@TXi0vhvWsOGbm4R@axwBF@/KXrDYTgDGrtWE06DIjG6IOT0iqkhuIOoDYvRCqjdEFjeBQYmgtpos@myfzeIlhxtnoZvz/ujL6E1wZKVf2tvgSSl@kK@Pd7ItVt5iM02NWAwQaEagCurfNzupFu6cyj6lAm9eu0h/6sq02jE1JmUq0/Lf/Rl7mIEONlh90@ia61uauY8Mq69anf/qaoHrb6p6AuEbtrqBTIWFQ4ySsSRtpEiUQ0e1qMWHyZ3BP/KRkNpo175jZu0ixk3rXjlBDfhz0Dwxa3okrQ2h0WF2zAG3eO7i8eLj6LBzUGtpLQfSa0sF6yQu2lbwDW/cBgZY@pMH/0BChYfjErYh186/bIbM3CsBDXLXrY5NEDYKIfzFJD0J05UmA1afJLIIkCZ6pDjPlMJlO6SeaKC6hTHX24w72nDhisx13RFSmayB0g/KaPo9Sjs0qi/K72CWljgPfH2z8MYhuj/gfI5ZH1tSvcc/f/X8D)

```php
# Read a string, coerce to number by adding 0, and check if non-zero
: IF (+ 0 PROMPT) {
    # if it was non-zero, loop printing 1 forever
    : WHILE 1 {
        : OUTPUT 1
    }
    # else output 0 and exit.
    {
        : OUTPUT 0
    }
```

Old version which I wrote on my own:

```
;=wP;W+0wO1O0
```

There are a few ways to do this. Decided this way because of a certain theme.

Ungolfed version:

```ruby
# Read string into input
; = input PROMPT
# Coerce input to a number by adding 0, and loop while not 0
; WHILE (+ 0 input) {
    # Output 1 and a new line
    : OUTPUT 1
    # this is an infinite loop
}
# Otherwise, output 0 and a new line, and quit
: OUTPUT 0
```

If we allow excess newlines, this is an arguably superior program:

```
;=wP;W+0wOwOw
```

However, this prints two new lines because `PROMPT` includes the trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 10 bytes

This makes use of the fact that the input will be only 0 or 1:

```
λn?a:#∞n
```

Explanation:

```
λ        // input into the accumulator
 n       // print the accumulator
  ? :    // if-else statement (auto-closes to '?a:#∞n::')
   a     // if the accumulator evaluates to truthy (i.e. non-zero)...
     #∞  // ...loop forever...
       n // ...implicitly print the accumulator...
         // ...else do nothing
```

In other news, I really should make a custom charmap for barrel. With a custom charmap, I could shave off 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Squire](https://github.com/sampersand/squire), 47 bytes

```
x=inquire()whence l proclaim(x+" ")if"0"!=x{l:}
```

Whilst some languages have a `goto` keyword, Squire useth `whence`, **the opposite**. One might call it a `comefrom`. Squire also containeth a normal loop with `whilst`, but alas, it is impossible to useth this without enscribing `proclaim` twice.

If we accompany `whence` with `if`, we can create a loop that some call `do-whilst`.

Ungolfeth:

```php
# Inquire a line from ye standard input
x = inquire()
# Set a whence point
whence loop
# Proclaim x, followed by a space, to ye standard output
proclaim(x + " ")
# If x is not "0"
if "0" != x {
    # Loopeth ad infinitum
    loop:
}
```

Methinks this language is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

## Nim-Lang, <s>72</s>, <s>64</s>, <s>49</s>, 41 (credits to @hyper-neutrino and @Jo King) bytes

```
var a=readChar(stdin)
while a=='1':echo 1
echo 0
```

### Version with if-statement, with suggested edits:

```
if readChar(stdin)=='0':echo 0
else:
  while true:echo 1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nim, but could you remove some whitespace (e.g. after the two colons)? Also, does `if'0'==a` work instead? Also, is `while 1` allowed? That's a trick in Python but I don't know if Nim accepts that. Finally, could you use an if-else instead, or even better, if a is 1, while loop, and then just echo 0 at the end, since the while loop will never terminate anyway?

Comment: No, while 1: is not allowed, unfortunately. However, the space can be removed. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: do you actually need to assign to `a`? can you just use `readChar(stdin)` in the condition?

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), 41 bytes

[Based on answer by @unrelatedstring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185945/100411).
If you don't care for errors, won't you guys golf off the program easily?

```
DOWRITEIN.1DOCOMEFROM.1(1)PLEASEREADOUT.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FPzzIM8TV00/P0MXf2d/X1S3I31fPUMNQM8DH1THYNcjV0cU/NETP8P//KNcgfy4A)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 28 bytes

```bat
:1
@Echo(%1&Goto:%1
:0
```

uses input as output and script flow controller.

Answer (score 0):

## [makina](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/makina), 23 bytes

```
v>>P
>?EJ
U>PU
^0n<
;1<
```

### Explanation

The first automaton starts in the top left, and immediately goes down and right into the `?`, or if. The condition for the if is the `E`, or number input. Once input is given, the condition automaton jumps forwards and out of bounds, causing it to return its value. If that value is 0, or false, the first automaton turns left and goes into the top `P`, or print. The print spawns a new automaton going right, which jumps over the U-turn, goes left, into the `n`, or number. It reads the 0, turns up, does a U-turn, hits the semicolon (ending the number), and goes out of bounds, returning a 0 to the print. The first automaton then goes out of bounds and halts. However, if the value is 1, or true, the automaton turns right and proceeds directly into the `n`, goes left, reads the 1, and halts. Then, the first automaton goes out if the print, into the U-turn, making it go back to the arrow to the left of the print, starting the whole cycle again.

Answer (score 0):

## [SMALL](https://csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/small.html), 14 bytes

```
$->x{x=1?1!}0!
```

Ungolfed code:

```
$ -> x

{
    x = 1?
    1!
}

0!
```

We first read from stdin and store the input in x, with the following line.

```
$->x
```

We then enter an iteration, where we first compare if x is 1. If that's the case, we print 1. Since this check will never be false, this iteration will be infinite.

```
{
    x = 1?
    1!
}
```

If the condition in this iteration is false, the entire iteration stops and we go to the last line, which prints a single zero after which the program halts.

```
0!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), 67 bytes

```
I0S1M2V0G0
G-1G-1G-1G-1
O0

A0A0
A0C3G1G1A0
A0O1A0
A0A1G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

The top line takes input, then adds one to this number and multiplies it by two. For input 0 we now have 2 and for input 1 we have 4. This is used as the offset for the goto instruction. If we jump by two we end up at line three which prints zero and halts. If we jump by four, we get to line five and get to an fininite loop.

```
A0  A0
A0  C3 G1  G1  A0
A0  O1 A0
A0  A1 G-3 G-3 A0
G-3
```

This infinite loop simply prints one (on the third line in the loop: `O1`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://python.org), <s>59</s> 43 bytes

```python
if input()=="1":
 while 1:print(1)
print(0)
```

-16 by Seggan

Comment: This can be significantly golfed: no need for explicit `exit()`, and the `i` variable can be inlined.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that it was inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
?x(;
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

The `?` could be replaced with a `!` for the same effect.

```
?x(; # The program
?    # If
 x   # The input is truthy (i.e. 1)
  (; # Print the input forever
     # Otherwise print the condition (which was 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## nroff/troff, 27 bytes

Ties with [user100411's 27 bytes answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233556/113493). This version, however, does REALLY outputs 1's FOREVER for input 1, while previous version halts by stack overflow.

```
.de a
\\$1
.while \\$1 1
..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@J9XlJ@WpmBjo54IBOr/9VJSFRK5YmJUDLn0yjMyc1IVQGwFIE/vv16iggEXkDDkAqn9DwA)

### Usage

```
.a 0
.a 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5 bytes

(actually 4.94 bytes, but the leaderboard doesn't take floats)

```
!)[1ZK
```

(No ATO link since that's on an outdated version)

##### Explanation

```python
!)[1ZK  # Implicit input
!       # Push `not input` (i.e., 1 if input == 0; 0 if input == 1)
 )      # Break if the top of the stack is truthy (i.e. input == 0)
        # Since the stack is filled with 0s at the start, 0 is implicitly output in this case
  [     # while True:
   1ZK  #  print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language) Assembly, 12 Bytes

`7+2*IJTGE1TO`

Answer (score 0):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)) `i` <s>140</s> <s>85</s> 29 Chars or \$29\log_{256}(3)\approx\$ 5.75 Bytes

```
(,,((()),()),,((()),())(),())
```

[TIO](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=i&code=(,,((()),()),,((()),())(),())&stdin=0&)

Answer (score 0):

## AArch64 machine code + Linux syscalls, 40 bytes

```
00: 528007e8  mov   w8, #63    // read()
04: 2a1f03e0  mov   w0, wzr    // 0 = stdin
08: 910003e1  mov   x1, sp     // to stack
0c: d2800022  mov   x2, #1     // 1 byte
10: d4000001  svc   #0         // syscall, should mov x0, #1
14: 394003e9  ldrb  w9, [sp]   // load byte
18: 52800808  mov   w8, #64    // write()
1c: d4000001  svc   #0         // syscall, w0 = 1 = stdout
20: 3707ffe9  tbnz  w9, #0, 1c // loop last instruction if byte & 1
24: d65f03c0  ret
```

Can be used as a `void (void)`, or an `int (void)` such as `main()`, returning 1.
If you want to use it as `_start()` without segfaults, replace the `ret` with:

```
24: 52800ba8  mov   w8, #93    // exit()
28: d4000001  svc   #0         // syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 28 bytes

ForWhile does not have infinite loops,
so to output indefinitely the program has to continuously copy its source code behind the instruction pointer.

`_:49=[{}1+20[:@;20-$1-:)'#]#`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=Xzo0OT1be30xKzIwWzpAOzIwLSQxLTopJyNdIw==&in=MQ==)

## Explanation

```
_                            \ read a character from standard input
 :49=                        \ check if it is one
     [                    ]# \ if the character is not one, print it
      {}1+20[:@;20-$1-:)'#   \ infinite 'loop'
      {}                     \ get the current instruction pointer (empty procedure)
        1+                   \ offset instruction pointer such that it points to start of code block
          20[:@;20-$1-:)     \ copy code starting at {  to position after #
                        '#   \ print the second value on the stack (the character read from standard input)
```

---

## ForWhile, 42 bytes

[This version](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=Xzo0OT1bMzQoITskMS1de30xMCs6MzRbOkA7MzQtJDEtOik0OSMkLl0j&in=MQ==)
has constant memory usage

`_:49=[34(!;$1-]{}10+:34[:@;34-$1-:)49#$.]#`

it works similarly to the shorter version, but additionally deletes the old code and cleans up the stack

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```rkt
#!racket
(let l([n(read)])(print n)(if(= n 0)(void)(l n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@f9fWbEIzOLSyEktUcjRiM7TKEpNTNGM1dQoKMrMK1HI09TITNOwVchTMNDUKMvPTNHUyAEKamr@/28AAA)

---

### Explanation

Our program creates a recursive named `let` statement that loop if `n` is not equal to 0. On the first iteration, we read user input into `n`. We print `n`s value and test whether we should loop or not.

```rkt
#lang racket

(let loop ([n (read)])
  (print n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (void)
      (loop n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Intcode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/intcode), 19 bytes | 8 ints

Everyone's favorite intcode computer from the [Advent Of Code 2019](https://adventofcode.com/2019).

```
3,0,4,0,1005,0,2,99
```

Answer (score 0):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 11 bytes

Takes input through the `-i` flag

```
:?`n;
 !`:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/9/KPiHPmktBMcEq7///f/kFJZn5ecX/dTP/GwIA)

Comment: ... wouldn't just `v` and `>` work better than using dive (though that ends up identical to a normal ><> solution)? also, you can move the last `n` to the start of the line

Answer (score 0):

## Uiua, 5 bytes

```
⍢⟜&p∘
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2i4p-cJnDiiJgKRiAwCiMgY2xpY2sgc2V0dGluZ3MgaWNvbiwKIyBzZXQgbWF4IGV4ZWN1dGlvbiB0aW1lCiMgdG8gMC41IHNlY29uZHMgb3Igc28KRiAxCg==)

Do `⍢` without popping `⟜` print `&p` while top of stack is 1 `∘`.

Answer (score -1):

**Ruby, 22 bytes**

```
->(n){n==0?0:loop{p1}}
```

Answer (score -2):

## Python 2, <strike>43</strike> <strike>42</strike> 41 bytes

```
x=raw_input();print x
while x>'0':print x
```

Got a syntax error at the while loop if I tried to run it as a one-liner. Not really sure why.

EDIT: Knocked off a semicolon.

Knocked off ANOTHER semicolon that I put on there because I've been looking at C too much lately.

Comment: You could use `x=input()` and then `x>0`