# Signal-Interrupting Quines

Tags: code-golf, quine

Quining has a long history - if you haven't heard of it, click the tag and read up a little on it.

### Your Task

Output an infinite series of `1`s (with no other spacing [newlines, spaces, etc.]) UNTIL SIGINT (typically CTRL-C) is called. When it is called, output the program source.

### Rules

- It must be a valid quine:

  - No reading source from the disk.
  - See all other [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) relating to quines.
- You may use any language.
- As this is a code golf, the shortest answer wins!

Comment: "Language": [Truth Machine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732) Source: `1`

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ That's pretty great, actually. I'm not sure if I'd accept it, because it doesn't output the source at the end, it just stops putting out the source.

Comment: How do you know the last character is not the program outputting its source? :P (It's a joke answer, anyway)

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ API, maybe?

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 76 bytes

```py
s="while 1:\n try:print(end='1')\n except:-print('s=%r;exec(s)'%s)";exec(s)
```

Note that the byte count includes a trailing newline. This also uses `-print` to error out after quining.

Comment: `s="try:\n while 1:print(end='1')\nexcept:print('s=%r;exec(s)'%s)";exec(s)`saves 2 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
.xf!p1)jN*2]".xf!p1)jN*2]
```

A modification of the standard Pyth quine to add a try-except function.

Comment: Would using # work for this? It would save 2 bytes.

Comment: @MikeBufardeci I tried that, but couldn't get to work. Give it a shot yourself.

Answer (score 3):

## [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/forum), <s>488</s> <s>429</s> 362 bytes

My brain hurts, this is too meta.

```
$1=BinaryToString
$2=Chr(34)
$s="FileWrite('a','#include<Misc.au3>'&@LF&'Do'&@LF&'ToolTip(1)'&@LF&'Until _IsPressed(Chr(49)&Chr(66))')+RunWait(@AutoItExe&' a')"
Execute($s)
$x="$1=BinaryToString\n$2=Chr(34)\n%sExecute($s)\n$x=%s\nClipPut(StringFormat($x,$1(0x223D7324)&$s&$1(0x0A0D22),$2&$x&$2))"
ClipPut(StringFormat($x,$1(0x223D7324)&$s&$1(0x0A0D22),$2&$x&$2))
```

This is quite interesting in the way that it compiles a child-process which in return keeps outputting 1 to the ToolTip API until ESC is pressed. If ESC is pressed, the child process kills itself and the parent (this quine) resumes execution and dumps it's source *to the clipboard*. You have to run this from the editor.

<sub>BTW: This creates an auxiliary file 'a' on your disk.</sub>

Comment: Auxiliary files! \o/

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>239</s> <s>221</s> <s>206</s> 172 Bytes

Definitely could be a lot shorter, but I had to post something on PPCG *eventually*.

```
*s="*s=%c%s%c,r;h(s){r=1;}main(){signal(2,h);while(!r)printf(%c1%c);printf(s,34,s,34,34,34);}",r;h(s){r=1;}main(){signal(2,h);while(!r)printf("1");printf(s,34,s,34,34,34);}
```

Compiles with gcc 5.2.1 (with various warnings).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 206 bytes

```
import Control.Exception;main=catch(putStr o)e;o='1':o;e::SomeException->IO();e _=putStr(s++show s);s="import Control.Exception;main=catch(putStr o)e;o='1':o;e::SomeException->IO();e _=putStr(s++show s);s="
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 339 Bytes

```
using d=System.Console;class c{static bool k=1>0;static void Main(){d.CancelKeyPress+=delegate{k=1<0;var s="using d=System.Console;class c{{static bool k=1>0;static void Main(){{d.CancelKeyPress+=delegate{{k=1<0;var s={0}{1}{0};d.WriteLine(s,(char)34,s);}};while(k){{d.Write(1);}}}}}}";d.WriteLine(s,(char)34,s);};while(k){d.Write(1);}}}
```

Comment: Nice Trick - thanks @LegionMammal978

Comment: Also, `delegate` can be replaced with `()=>`. Why isn't `k` a local variable?

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5.10+, 64 bytes

```
perl -E '$_=q{$SIG{INT}=sub{say"\$_=q{$_};eval";die};{print 1;redo}};eval'
```

Requires Perl 5.10+ for `say`, which can be enabled with either `-M5.010` or `-E`.

### How it works

This is yet another variation of the following quine, which I seem to use on every quine challenge:

```
$_=q{say"\$_=q{$_};eval"};eval
```

Broken down:

```
perl -E '
    $_=q{                        # store contents of quine in $_
        $SIG{INT}=sub{           # install handler for SIGINT
            say"\$_=q{$_};eval"; # print quine
            die                  # break out of eval
        };
        {
            print 1;             # print "1"
            redo                 # restart block
        }
    };
    eval                         # eval $_, executing its contents as code
'
```

Comment: Oops, initially was printing the `1`s separated by newlines. Fixed at a cost of 2 bytes.