# Do you need a cup holder?

Tags: code-golf, hardware

You're going to replicate the 90's cup holder joke software.

Here's what's it did, and you have to do:

- Display the message `Do you need a cup holder?`
- If the user confirms, enter an infinite loop that keeps opening the CDROM drive.
- If the user doesn't confirm, silently exit.

You may display the message using either a console message (confirmation is <kbd>y</kbd>, decline is <kbd>n</kbd>), or display a message window with the two options "Yes" and "No". You can assume the default (or most common) CDROM drive (`D:` on Windows, `/cdrom` on linux etc.). Standard loopholes (except built-ins) are forbidden. No additional input nor output may be involved. If your PC has no physical drive, or another "style" of tray, make sure the program is valid.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins.

Trivia: The loop is there to prevent anyone from closing the drive. On desktop drives, the re-open command will be sent while the drive is closing, therefore staying open and not "spilling the coffee".

Comment: Minus the necessary CD eject system call, I think this is strikingly similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine

Comment: I think the requirement to interact with the hardware makes this sufficiently distinct from Implement a Truth Machine.

Comment: FYI http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/8478 (specifically "having long fixed output strings that benefit from compression.").

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, <s>115</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

This was written on Mac OS X but it should work on other BSD-based systems as well.

```bash
echo Do you need a cup holder?;sed 1q|grep y&&yes drutil\ eject|sh
```

We `echo` the prompt, get input with `set 1q`, and determine whether the user confirmed with `grep y`. If the user said `y`, we pipe the infinite output of `yes` with the string `drutil eject` to the shell, which will continuously eject the disk tray.

Saved **50 bytes** thanks to Digital Trauma!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma You are the bash master!

Comment: Can you save bytes by replacing the `sed` and `grep` with `read`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `drutil tray eject`?

Comment: @VoteToClose `drutil eject` is a synonym for `drutil tray open`. It works as expected. ;)

Comment: @CousinCocaine I was using `read` in a previous revision, but then I'd need an equality check, which makes it longer overall. You can take a look at the revision history to see what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

## Vitsy + Mac OSX bash, 55 bytes

```
'?redloh puc a deen uoy oD'ZWb2^/([1m]
<,'drutil eject'
```

Expects input as y or n. If it is n, it will execute line 2 (infinite loop with the shell command), otherwise, it will halt.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (3.5) 84 bytes

```
import os
i=input("Do you need a cup holder?")
while i=='y':os.system("eject cdrom")
```

On linux

*edit: fix bytes count ;)*

Comment: FYI: I noticed this because I'm using [this script](https://stackapps.com/q/6772/54015), which (among other things) adds a byte/char counter above blocks of code on PPCG.

Answer (score 0):

### [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/forum), 85 bytes

```
If MsgBox(4,0,"Do you need a cup holder?")=7 Then Exit
Do
CDTray("D:","open")
Until 0
```

<sub>No one will ever answer anything in AutoIt anyway :)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3.5 on Windows 7, 135 Bytes

```
import ctypes
r=input('Do you need a cup holder?')
while r=='y':ctypes.windll.WINMM.mciSendStringW('set cdaudio door open',None,0,None)
```