# Programming Less-Than, Greater-Than and Equal-To functions using Restricted Source

Tags: number, tips, atomic-code-golf, logic

I'm currently working with a branchless language which does not have native Less-Than, Greater-Than or Equal-To functions. I do however have `min`, `max` and `abs` functions and standard arithmetic (`+`, `-`, `/` and `*`) available to me.

I'd like to create these three functions (as `L(a, b)`, `G(a, b)` and `E(a, b)` respectively, which will output `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`. So, for example, `L(3, 7)` would return `1` for `true` whereas `G(3, 7)` would return `0` for `false`, and `E(3, 7)` would also return `0`, etc.

The `min` and `max` functions only allow you to pass two parameters, `a` and `b`, and then spits out the respective minimum or maximum of the two parameters. The `abs` function takes the one parameter and returns the absolute value.

I've postulated that given that the `min(a, b)` is equivalent to:

`L(a,b) * a + (1 - L(a,b)) * b`

It would stand to reason that:

`L(a,b) = (min(a,b) - b) / (a - b)`

and similarly:

`max(a,b) = G(a,b) * a + (1 - G(a,b)) * b`

therefore:

`G(a,b) = (max(a,b) - b) / (a - b)`

But this is where I get stumped because, I'm not sure how to account for the possibility of `a-b` equalling `0` in both instances, which as a result stumps me on how to approach the `E(a, b)` function.

So my question is this... Given that I only currently have access to basic arithmetic functions as well as `min(a,b)`, `max(a,b)` and `abs(a)`, and because of the language being branchless (therefore no loops), is there a way to programmatically account for the `a-b` divide-by-zero issue such that if I do have a scenario where `a == b` that these functions can return zero for either `L()` or `G()`, otherwise output the original equations I have derived, and also be able to provide code for `E(a, b)`?

Given that this is fairly generic (hey, I've written it in psuedocode!) I'd appreciate some insight on how to proceed. In this case, the solution needs to work with both integers as well as floats.

Context: This is research for a personal project I'm working on relating to binary registers, thus the need for 1's and 0's for output and I'm kinda stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're going for least number of tokens or something in addition to restricted source?

Comment: Also, are these numbers integers, doubles, or something else?

Comment: How is `/` defined exactly? If the numbers are integers, is it floored division or round-towards-zero?

Comment: @Bubbler, this is the problem I'm facing, I've never had the situation where a division by zero would occur. I've just tried to replicate such an event and it just fails quietly. I'm trying to work out how best to approach this.

Also WRT to division, there's no known flooring algorithm set at this point.

Comment: @user They can be integers or floats... uncertain if doubles have been considered. It's restricted because these are the only current functions I have available. I don't have any comparators; min, max and abs are the only functions I have at my disposal aside from the basic arithmetic functions.

Comment: `E(a,b)=1-abs(a-b)/max(eps,abs(a-b))` with `eps` the smallest number > 0 ?

Comment: Related: [an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204949/78410) to [Build a Turing-incomplete language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204891/78410). Having certain operations allows to solve quite a large class of problems without loops or branching.

Comment: @MarcMush, I'm not familiar with `eps`, is that like some error precision factor?

Comment: it depends on what number representation you are using, if it's 64bits, it should be 5e-324, 32bits is 1e-45, with integers it's 1, if you can have arbitrary small numbers, it doesn't work

Comment: it's to avoid a division by zero when a=b

Comment: To my understanding, you cannot get discontinuous functions from a few continuous functions. So `eps` is always needed if you are looking for some answers to floating point errors. (Answers for integers already has `1` as their `eps`.)

Comment: @tsh Division is not continuous at zero denominator. The problem is that it isn't even defined there, which makes it continuous *within its domain*, so I guess your point is still valid. Integer division is not continuous though (it's a step function), and my integer GE exploits that. OTOH, my floating GE quickly increases from 0 to 1 between `-eps` and `0` :)

Comment: @Bubbler by saying continuous, I mean continuous on its domain.

Comment: I'm pretty unclear on what the task here is.  You seem to not express the number types involved, and you don't seem to explain what the output of the desired functions are.  Less than and greater than are propositions, normally when taken as functions they return a boolean or truth value, but here it is pretty clear you want them to return a number instead.  I haven't figured out exactly how that output is supposed to represent a truth value.  Overall I get the sense that you don't know exactly what you are want to ask and I have trouble guessing for you.

Comment: @WheatWizard That’s okay as Bubbler has already provided the solution I need. This wasn’t a code challenge in the traditional sense that we normally pose. But knowing the analytical minds of my fellow code golfers I knew they were more capable of solving the conundrum I was facing than anyone outside this subdomain…

Comment: @WheatWizard how do boolean values different from single bit integers?

Comment: @tsh Ideally if you are using single bit integers you want to say which value is true and which value is false, but more importantly the question doesn't mention single bit integers anywhere.  And would even I assume the numeric type used is not single bit integers otherwise (in the 0 is false 1 is true case) `a-b` would be able to check if they are equal, `a*(b+1)` would check be GT, you wouldn't even need `min` or `max`.

Comment: @WheatWizard the language I have been working on, doesn't know booleans like `true` and `false`, and is also branchless and so standard IF statements, switch statements, etc are out the window. So to accommodate that I have had to work with scenarios which can make use of single bit values as a means of turning on and off certain components that build up a value: eg. `f(a) * A + (1- f(a)) * B`. The language is still fairly primitive, so the answer Bubbbler has provided has actually opened it up considerably.

Comment: If you want an expression that gives back either 1 or 0 then what is wrong with the eternal classic: `1-min(1, abs(a-b))`?  Either way the question to be clear you should include information about the desired inputs and outputs in the challenge.  But it seems you are happy with the current state so I don't see much benefit in explaining all this to me.  We can just leave the question closed.

Comment: @WheatWizard number is just a few more bytes than boolean. Also in most computer languages, a boolean costs 1 bytes (8 bits) instead of 1 bit. I don’t see it may be unclear that how to convert between boolean concepts and integers, and integers and reals. You just need to padding many 0s. Also I would consider false=0, true=1 as default mapping. It should only be clarified if it not follow such convenience.

Comment: @tsh  Some languages treat any number other than zero as true and zero as false, some only consider the least significant bit of the number.   It *seems* from the comments that the OP doesn't want numbers other than 1 and 0 to be output.  Except maybe not? Since the normal solutions seem to be discounted. This information should be in the question, along with other pertinent information.  That is all I am saying.

Comment: @WheatWizard do you mean that “ I'd like to create these three functions (as L(a, b), G(a, b) and E(a, b) respectively, which will output 0 for false and 1 for true.”?

Comment: @tsh I'm not sure why you are pinging me here.  It seems like the OP is happy with Bubbler's answer, and I certainly am not terribly interested in figuring out what the OP meant.  The question as it stands is missing information and I closed it.  I'd reopen it if the question were fully clarified.  If you have some point to this it is totally lost on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Integers and round-to-zero integer division

```
// 1 if x >= y, 0 otherwise
GE(x, y) = (x - y + 1) / (abs(x - y) + 1)
LE(x, y) = GE(y, x)
E(x, y) = GE(x, y) * LE(x, y)
L(x, y) = LE(x, y) - E(x, y) = 1 - GE(x, y)
G(x, y) = GE(x, y) - E(x, y) = 1 - LE(x, y)
```

If `x - y` is negative, `x - y + 1` has smaller magnitude than `abs(x - y) + 1`, so the division rounds to 0.

If `x - y` is zero or higher, `x - y + 1` is the same as `abs(x - y) + 1`, so the result is 1.

## Integers and floored integer division

```
GE(x, y) = (x - y + abs(x - y) + 1) / (abs(x - y) * 2 + 1)
```

If `x - y` is negative, the numerator is fixed at 1, but the denominator is at least 3. Therefore the result is zero.

If `x - y` is zero or positive, the numerator and the denominator are the same, so the result is 1.

## Floating-point numbers

MarcMush pointed out a possible use of `eps`, the smallest representable number greater than 0. GE can be implemented for floating-point numbers using it:

```
GE(x, y) = (max(x - y, -eps) + eps)/(abs(x - y) + eps)
```

I haven't found any way without `eps` or the floor function. (If `floor` is available, flooring the second solution works for floats.) tsh pointed out that we can't get a (true) discontinuous function from a bunch of continuous functions, so I'm pretty sure it is impossible without `eps` or an additional built-in that provides discontinuity.

Assuming an IEEE floating-point representation, the solution above is expected to give exact results (exactly 0 or exactly 1) for all non-NaN, non-infinite floating-point values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Given that I’m after integers and floats, this fits the bill nicely… thanks

Comment: `L(x,y)==LE(x,y)-E(x,y)==LE(x,y)(1-GE(x,y))` but surely the `LE(x,y)` becomes redundant so you can just write `L(x,y)==1-GE(x,y)`?

Comment: @Neil Yeah, of course.

Answer (score 4):

This answer only works on integer values :)

### Test Zero

We all know that

$$ (t+1)(t-1)=t^2-1 $$
$$ t\cdot t-(t+1)(t-1)=1 $$

As long as \$t\$ is integer.

$$ t\cdot t-|t+1|\cdot|t-1| = \begin{cases}
    1 & t\ne 0 \\
    -1 & t = 0\\
  \end{cases} $$

So we have:

```
isZero(t) = (t*t-abs(t+1)*abs(t-1)+1)/2
```

### Build others

And then, you can have

```
GreaterThanOrEqual(a, b) = isZero(max(b-a, 0))
LessThanOrEqual(a, b) = GreaterThanOrEqual(b, a)
Equal(a, b) = GreaterThanOrEqual(a, b) * LessThanOrEqual(a, b)
GreaterThan(a, b) = GreaterThanOrEqual(a, b) - Equal(a, b)
LessThan(a, b) = LessThanOrEqual(a, b) - Equal(a, b)
```

Comment: In fact `isZero` really detects whether a `1>t>-1`, so it will also work for non-integers, if you interpret it that way.

Comment: @SeanD for \$ t \in (-1,1) \$, \$ t^2-|t+1|\cdot |t-1|=2t^2-1 \$

Answer (score -2):

Assuming floor division:
E(x,y) = (1 - abs(x-y)) / (1 + abs(x-y))
L(a,b) = E(min(a,b), a) - E(a,b)
G(a,b) = E(max(a,b), a) - E(a,b)