# Tips for golfing in 1+

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in 1+? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to 1+ (e.g. "remove unnecessary whitespace" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: [This](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B) 1+?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Yes.

Comment: Are there actually any answers on this site that use 1+? I'm all for tips pages, but they don't seem necessary if no-one has ever even used the language here.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oops. I will do it, then. (Though, because it's a Turing-tarpit, it would be very hard to do simple tasks for usual languages, e. g. ROT13.)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Also I have to say, because of my special geographic location, I'm without access to tumblr - and thus without access to the official interpreter. So all programs I made are not verified.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Why is that hosted on Tumblr??? That's bizarre. Here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/DJMcMayhem/c7186ae2890b5c8a54e38ba7a595a7d5

Answer (score 4):

## Subroutines can have empty names

`(|1+1<)` is a valid definition for a subroutine, invoked as `()`.

Answer (score 2):

## Instead of pushing 0 and compare, do something to other numbers

As 1 is the only literal in 1+ and there's no minus operation, pushing 0 would be expensive (`11+1<`). A better choice would be change other numbers, so 1 becomes a "relative" 0. For example, if you want to flip a bit, instead of `11+1<<`, you can `1+1<`.

Answer (score 2):

## Use comments for conditionals

Found this while exploiting interpreter features. Apparently Parcly Taxel thinks comments and conditionals are similar because both of them begins with "co". The comment indicators `[]` are actually instructions because there's no such thing called parsers in 1+.

This trick can sometimes save you and a few bytes from the comparison mess.

Found while exploiting interpreter features, then [made a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208961/87986) with it.