# Introduce Your Language!

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a string as input, and prints `Hello (input), I'm (language name)`.

### Examples

**Python:**
Input: `Oliver`
Output: `Hello Oliver, I'm Python`

**C++:**
Input: `Jacob`
Output: `Hello Jacob, I'm C++`

etc.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the lowest number of bytes wins.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=94485,OVERRIDE_USER=12537;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: @BetaDecay The output is different and the input is different. Therefore, the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I strongly disagree: they're basically the same question with a trivial difference

Comment: @BetaDecay they're different as the birthday one is constant output - no input

Comment: @muddyfish The addition of the input isn't sufficient to distinguish this from the birthday challenge in my opinion. If you want to be picky, this is a half-dupe of cat and a half-dupe of happy birthday. Two half-dupes with a trivial combination makes a whole dupe.

Comment: @Mego It's not, because that requires it to print only on a specific day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sing Happy Birthday to your favourite programming language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/sing-happy-birthday-to-your-favourite-programming-language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [pl](http://github.com/quartata/pl-lang), 15 bytes

```
Hello _, I'm pl
```

[Try it online!](http://pl.tryitonline.net/#code=SGVsbG8gXywgSSdtIHBs&input=RGVubmlz)

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 29 bytes

```python
"Hello {}, I'm Python".format
```

Strings methods for the win! The built-in method format of a string substitutes the arguments (here a single string) into any replacement fields (here `{}`).

Usage:

```python
f = "Hello {}, I'm Python".format 
print f("xnor")
```

```
Hello xnor, I'm Python
```

Previous 30-byte:

```python
"Hello %s, I'm Python".__mod__
```

Comment: You can remove the exclamation point.

Answer (score 5):

## Assembly (x86-64, Linux), <s>217</s> 205 bytes

*4927 segmentation faults later...*

```assembly
.global main
.data
s:.ascii"Hello %qs, I'm Assembly\n"
f:.ascii"%qs"
i:.ascii""
main:mov $i,%rsi
mov $f,%rdi
mov $0,%rax
call scanf
mov $0,%rax
mov $i,%rsi
mov $s,%rdi
call printf
end:mov $0,%rax
call exit
```

Doesn't work for inputs with a length greater than 7, because this exceeds the memory limits of a quadword(?). Also, because I'm a noob in Assembly.

#### Explanation:

```assembly
.global main

.data

output_string: .ascii "Hello %qs, I'm Assembly\n"
format_input: .ascii "%qs"
input_string: .ascii ""

main:
    mov $input_string, %rsi     # Place the memory address to the second argument
    mov $format_input, %rdi     # Place the format string to the first argument
    mov $0, %rax                # Set RAX to 0
    call scanf                  # Call scanf with RDI and RSI as the arguments
                    
    mov $0, %rax                # Set RAX to 0
    mov $input_string, %rsi     # Place the input string to the second argument
    mov $output_string, %rdi    # Place the output format to the first argument
    call printf                 # Call printf with RDI and RSI as the arguments

end:
    mov $0, %rax                # Set RAX to 0 (which is the exit code)
    call exit                   # Call the exit function
```

Save in a file called *myProgram.s* and do the following:

```
$ gcc -o myProgram myProgram.s
$ ./myProgram
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```
”Ÿ™ ÿ, I'm 05AB1E
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdxbjihKIgw78sIEknbSAwNUFCMUU&input=RW1pZ25h)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 88 bytes

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("Hello "+a[0]+", I'm Java!");}}
```

Takes input on first command-line argument. Verbose Java is verbose.

Comment: You can write a function/method instead of a full program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“' ṗr>ƊḳȧT°ḋZ»Ỵj
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcJyDhuZdyPsaK4bizyKdUwrDhuItawrvhu7Rq&input=&args=RGVubmlz)

#### How it works

Call the argument of the main link **s**.

```
“' ṗr>ƊḳȧT°ḋZ»
```

represents an integer in bijective base 256 that encodes a sequence of dictionary words and/or characters. In this specific case, it encodes the dictionary word **Hello**, followed by **¶, I'm** with a leading space (**¶** represents a linefeed), followed by the dictionary word **Jelly** with a leading space.

The result is as follows.

```
Hello 
, I'm Jelly
```

The `Ỵ` atoms splits this string at linefeeds, yielding the following array.

```
["Hello ", "", I'm Jelly"]
```

Finally, the `j` atom joins that array, using the string **s** as separator.

Answer (score 3):

## Cheddar, 26 bytes

```
"Hello %s I'm Cheddar"&(%)
```

Comment: Functional approach ftw

Answer (score 3):

### [Straw](http://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), 25 bytes

```
(Hello b, I'm Straw!)b</>
```

[Try it online!](http://straw.tryitonline.net/#code=KEhlbGxvIGIsIEknbSBTdHJhdyEpYjwvPg&input=VHV4)

Simple regex substitution.

Answer (score 3):

## Minecraft, 27 bytes

```
say Hello @p, I'm Minecraft
```

`say` Prints the given string and replaces `@p` with the name of the nearest player

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 24 bytes

```
'Hello %s, I''m MATL'jYD
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J0hlbGxvICVzLCBJJydtIE1BVEwnallE&input=U3VldmVy)

Answer (score 2):

## [Element](http://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 28 bytes

```
Hello\ _\,\ I\'m\ Element..`
```

(link to [TIO](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=SGVsbG9cIF9cLFwgSVwnbVwgRWxlbWVudC4uYA&input=UGhpTm90UGk))

Woo! Two months since this site's previous Element answer!

Comment: Am I right in assuming that \ is the escape character, and that it escapes the spaces? If so, why do they have to be escaped?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Normally, two words separated by a space are pushed as two separate tokens.  For example, `2 3` pushes a `2` and a `3`, while `2\ 3` pushes `2 3`.  There's no special processing to distinguish literal words from literal numbers, they are all represented by scalars in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 25 bytes

```
@echo Hello %*, I'm Batch
```

Conveniently `'` isn't a quote character in Batch.

Comment: The spelling was changed in the question to remove a `!`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Serves me right for copying from the `sh` answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html), 73 bytes

```
Hello✖➕⏫, I'm Emotinomicon⏪⏬⏩
```

If you go to the [Interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html) you can generate an explanation

Thanks to [@Oliver Ni](http://www.oliverni.com) for make me notice that bug that Emotinomicon removes whitespaces at the end of the String literal

Comment: I count 50 bytes

Comment: You're right I missed that although I will add two bytes back to add whitespaces between the name and the literals.

Comment: You need a space after Hello. It is currently printing `HelloOliver, I'm Emotinomicon`.

Answer (score 1):

## sh, 24 bytes

```
echo "Hello $1, I'm sh!"
```

Comment: I'm getting `sh.exe": !": event not found` but that might be windows only

Comment: Works for me on void linux.

Comment: In pure sh you can probably use `\'` and remove the quotes to save a byte. Other shell versions probably want you to quote the `!` too, but at least that doesn't end up costing anything overall.

Comment: Although as @ConorO'Brien points out the `!` is no longer part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 21 bytes

```
"Hello , I'm Pyke"6Q:
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%22Hello+%2C+I%27m+Pyke%226Q%3A&input=Oliver)

Answer (score 1):

## Nim, 40 bytes

```
echo "Hello "&stdin.readAll&", I'm Nim!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 29 Bytes

```
<?="Hello $argv[1], I'm PHP";
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 21 bytes

```
X6"Hello , I'm Pyth"Q
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=X6%22Hello+%2C+I%27m+Pyth%22Q&input=%22Bob%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```
x=>`Hello ${x}, I'm JavaScript`
```

Simple enough. `${x}` is inline `x`, the argument.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>50</s> 39 bytes

```c
f(char*s){printf("Hello %s, I'm C",s);}
```

Comment: A function would be considerably shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 22 bytes

```
', I''m J',~'Hello '&,
```

This is a fork:

```
', I''m J' ,~ 'Hello '&,
```

`'Hello '&,` prepends `Hello` and `', I''m J' ,~` appends `, I'm J`.

Example run:

```
   (', I''m J',~'Hello '&,)'Conor'
Hello Conor, I'm J
```

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
"Ξ\x08£C¦i, I‘m Jolf
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Is6eCMKjQ8KmaSwgSeKAmG0gSm9sZg&input=Q29ub3I) Replace `\x08` with the literal character.

`¦i` is interpolated input, and `Ξ\x08£C` is compressed form of `Hello` with a trailing space. This outputs, for input `Conor`:

```
Hello Conor, I'm Jolf
```

---

Alternatively, for 23 bytes:

```
"Hello ¦i, I‘m ¦ᖒ
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 23 bytes

```
[, I'm dc!]?[Hello ]PPP
```

dc doesn't provide any means of getting raw strings, so you have to wrap your input in `[`brackets`]`. For example:

```
$ dc hello.dc <<< [Daniel]
Hello Daniel, I'm dc!
```

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 27 bytes

```
"Hello "\", I'm GolfScript"
```

Takes input from STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 32 bytes

```
puts "Hello #{$*[0]}, I'm Ruby"
```

Save as `intro.rb`, run as `ruby intro.rb <name>`.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 25 bytes

```
n=>s"Hello $n, I'm Scala"
```

To use it, assign this function to a variable.

```
val greeting = n=>s"Hello $n, I'm Scala"
greeting("Jacob")
```

I didn't expect that you can drop the type annotation if the parameter is of type `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 33 bytes

```
Fn.new{|x|"Hello %(x), I'm Wren"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaiRskjNScnX0FVo0JTR8FTPVchHKhWqfZ/cGVxSWquXnlRZkmqBkibXnJiTo6Gkk9iXnppYnqqkqbmfwA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                      } // New anonymous function
          "Hello %(x), I'm Wren"  // Surrounding the input w/ Hello & wren
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 33 bytes

```
lambda a:"Hello %s, I'm Python"%a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://rjhunjhunwala.github.io/S.I.L.O.S/) <s>112</s> 110 bytes

```
loadLine 
def : lbl
print Hello 
a=256
:a
x=get a
if x c
if 1 e
:c
printChar x
a+1
if x a
lble
print , I'm S.I.L.O.S
```

It should be loosely readable. Just a trivial modification of the cat program

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=bG9hZExpbmUgCnByaW50IEhlbGxvIAphPTI1NgpsYmxhCng9Z2V0IGEKaWYgeCBjCmlmIDEgZQpsYmxjCnByaW50Q2hhciB4CmEgKyAxCmlmIHggYQpsYmxlCnByaW50ICwgSSdtIFMuSS5MLk8uUw&input=&args=dGVzdA)

Comment: You can remove the spaces in `a + 1`

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 21 bytes

```
"Hello "l", I'm CJam"
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IkhlbGxvICJsIiwgSSdtIENKYW0i&input=THVpcw)

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 22 bytes

```sed
s/.*/Hello &, I'm sed/
```

**[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=cy8uKi9IZWxsbyAmLCBJJ20gc2VkLw&input=UFBDRw)**

**Run:**

```sh
sed -f hello.sed <<< "PPCG"
```

**Output:**

```
Hello PPCG, I'm sed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 360 bytes

```
0 * * l 1
1 _ [ l 2
2 _ o l 3
3 _ l l 4
4 _ l l 5
5 _ e l 6
6 _ H * 7
7 [ _ r 8
7 * * r *
8 _ ,  r 9
8 * * r *
9 _ _ r I
I _ I r '
' _ ' r m
m _ m r ~
~ _ _ r T
T _ T r u
u _ u r r
r _ r r i
i _ i r n
n _ n r g
g _ g r #
# _ _ r M
M _ M r a
a _ a r c
c _ c r h
h _ h r í
í _ i r ñ
ñ _ n r e
e _ e r ^
^ _ _ r C
C _ C r o
o _ o r d
d _ d r è
è _ e r halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?d5be61c361982522f9f2e6fcffac30ba)

Answer (score 0):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `j`, <del>17</del> 14 bytes

Short language names for the win. (I beat pl, and Dennis as well)

```
L~¶├'◄b₧û☻♪▼ºº
```

### Explanation

```
Hello "           % Start the output string with "Hello"
       a          % Insert the input onto the stack
        ", I'm W" % End the output string with ", I'm W"
                  % Implicit join whole stack at the end of the program
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 28 bytes

```
"Hello 
, I'm GolfScript"n/*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8kjNScnX4FLR8FTPVfBHSgTDJZRytPX@v/fJzEvvTQxPRUA)

## Explanation

```
"Hello 
, I'm GolfScript"    # Define the string to be inserted: "Hello \n, I'm GolfScript"
                 n/  # Split upon newlines             : ["Hello " ", I'm GolfScript"]
                   * # Join the array by input         : ["Hello input, I'm GolfScript"]
```