# Output the language name times the number of characters

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

## **Challenge:**

Your task is to use any language to output that language's name times the number of character's in its name.

- Use the common name or acronym of the language.
- If there are
  multiple versions of a language, you need not include the version number.
- The capitalization matters.

**Examples:**

```
PHP -> PHPPHPPHP
Java -> JavaJavaJavaJava
C++ -> C++C++C++
Python 3 -> PythonPythonPythonPythonPythonPython
JavaScript -> JavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScript
```

Comment: Tasks that depend on a language's name are a form of [disadvantaging  some languages by arbitrary criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/8478).

Comment: Oops, sorry, I wasn't aware of that. I will keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: As this is essentially outputting a fixed string, albeit different per language, I have tagged this with kolmogorov-complexity.

Comment: I think this challenge would have been a lot more interesting if the repetition count was supposed to be our bytecount...

Comment: This may be not a great challenge, but IMHO a question that has got 50+ answers deserves more upvotes...

Comment: And because it hasn't been said yet: Welcome to PPCG! I hope you stick around despite your probably confusing first impression of people telling you that this is not a good challenge while one answer after the other arrives.

Comment: I think you should get bonus score for having the same code run in multiple languages.

Comment: @corsiKa that would be interesting but we usually frown upon bonus scores in [tag:code-golf] challenges.

Comment: Let’s say I am writing this in Java. What’s stopping me from coding `System.out.print(“JavaJavaJavaJava”);`?

Comment: @DonielF nothing is stopping you from doing that. :)

Comment: Then I think this was a fairly poorly thought-out challenge. :/

Comment: @DonielF is that shortest though?

Comment: @DonielF Hardcoding the output of kolmogorov complexity challenges is always allowed. When that ends up being the shortest method it is not a super interesting challenge but for most of the non-single-byte-name languages it is not the shortest

Comment: Would it help to adjust the score as the length divided by the length of the program name? That wouldn't change the score for all the 1-byte language names but would bring others closer to lower scores.

Comment: 95 answers is a lot to change for scoring

Comment: IMO this is unclear. _Use the common name_ suggests that, for example, JS could be used for JavaScript. But what's to stop me saying that my language "Language" is more commonly known as "L"?

Comment: @FlipTack There's a difference between "common name" and "made up name". It's easy to verify if a language name is "common". For example, "J" is not a common name for "Java". Additionally, in order for a name to be common, surely it must be used in place of the language name at least in writing or colloquially. IMO, just because it isn't machine verifiable, doesn't make this criterion unclear.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Its not machine verifiable but its also not really human verifiable.  The challenge author doesn't really specify what they mean by common name. If "used in place of the language name at least in writing or colloquially" is the criterion then that ought to be said in the challenge.  And even then I still would feel that there are going to be cases on the edge, is it swipl, SWI-Prolog or just Prolog? Is clisp acceptable instead of common-lisp what about just lisp? Internet searches seem to reveal that these terms are used but they tend not to be used as much as other longer terms.

Comment: This is touched on in WheatWizard's comment but how should we deal with language's with different implementations? Should we use the language name or the implementations name? What if our code uses implementation specific features that don't exist in the language?

Comment: I think that a good clarification (that could get this reopened) would be something along the lines of `The "common name" is defined as the name that is on the language's main webpage/repository.` And you should remove `common name or acronym`, because then `JavaScript` = `JS`.

Comment: How is this unclear? I don't like the idea of this challenge, but I don't see why it should be put on hold as unclear.

Comment: @J843136028 Due to the fact that there's no way to define what the "common name" of a language is.

Comment: @MDXF Isn't it obvious what the name of a language is?

Comment: @J843136028 Issue is, it's hard to define objectively.

Answer (score 21):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
iV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzPs/38A)

Citing *Arnauld*, with Levenshtein distance of 1:

> I now have 15 seconds of experience in V programming. So, this may actually be golfable.

Comment: [2 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzPs/38A "V – Try It Online") :P

Comment: @totallyhuman It's indeed golfable.

Comment: Well, right language for the job! :)

Answer (score 16):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 16 bytes

```hs
h>>h
h="Haskell"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzP8POLoMrw1bJAyKm9D83MTNPwVahoLQkuKRIofj/v@S0nMT04v@6yQUFAA)

Applied on two lists, [`(>>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-) concatenates the second list with itself as often as the first list has elements.

---

#### Point-free (19 bytes)

```hs
id=<<(>>)$"Haskell"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzPzPF1sZGw85OU0XJAyKs9D83MTNPwVahoLQkuKRIofj/v@S0nMT04v@6yQUFAA)

`(id=<<)` is the same as [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join), but without the need for `import Control.Monad`.

Comment: I think you will need to count the `putStr` as well, or at least the `s=` that creates the nullary function.

Comment: @Bergi It is not needed according to the current [Meta consensus on this topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12924/56433), though I'd also be happy to change my answer if you have a good argument in favour of requiring a leading `s=`.

Comment: Ah, I already understood the "function" in [program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/7588) as a function *declaration* statement, not a function value *expression*.

Answer (score 16):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

I now have 15 seconds of experience in J programming. So, this may actually be golfable<sup>(1)</sup>.

```
echo'J'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/dS/3/fwA)

*<sup>(1)</sup> Edit: And of course it was. Thanks to @ConorO'Brien for  saving 2 bytes! Using a verb:*

### 5 bytes

```
'J'"_
```

Comment: Your answer became the one with most citations...

Comment: @user202729 Is there a hat for that?

Comment: You could also make this a verb (function) (5 bytes): `'J'"_`. The rank conjunction `"`, when it has a left-arg as a noun, it makes that noun into a constant verb returning that noun.

Answer (score 15):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 11 bytes

```
3.600525004
```

Explanation:

```
3.            Required prefix for all 4 programs.
  6            Set
   00            The cell at index 0
     52          To 52 (ASCII value for '4').
       5       Print
        00      The cell at index 0.
          4   Required suffix for all 4 programs.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M/n/31jPzMDA1MjUwMDk/38A)

Comment: I was just going to write that...

Answer (score 12):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 64 bytes

```
f={s="%1%1%1%1";format[s+"%1",format[s,"Operation Flashpoint"]]}
```

Since there is no official name for the scripting language, I'm using `Operation Flashpoint` as the name of the language.

**Call with:**

```
hint call f
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 8 bytes

```r
cat("R")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREMpSEnz/38A)

Comment: I think this can be done in 7 bytes, just `"R"` but called with `source(<program name>,ec=T)`

Comment: With the `ec=T` being like a compiler flag for +4 bytes

Comment: @Giuseppe I think using RGui, RStudio, or anything else with a REPL, you can just do `"R"`. I don't know if that counts.

Comment: @KSmarts outputs `[1] "R"` for me...

Comment: @KSmarts [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-should-a-full-program-in-r-be-invoked)

Answer (score 8):

## [C](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 12 bytes

```c
f(x){x="C";}
```

[Try it online! (GCC)](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KzusJWyVnJuva/cmZeck5pSqqCTXFJSma@XoYdV2ZeiUJuYmaehqZCNRdnQRGQn6aRpqGpac3FWZRaUlqUp2BgzVX7HwA)

Saved 3 bytes with help from [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729). C has been chosen strategically, but this is pretty much GCC-specific.

Comment: How can this function be used in a program?

Comment: @anatolyg See the tio link.

Comment: Can't say that's fair considering it requires other code to actually run.

Comment: @GalenNare Typically on this site, we allow function submissions. This is just a function.

Comment: Lovely way to generate lots of warnings though :)

Answer (score 8):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 2 bytes

```
”M
```

Single-letter languages have a clear advantage.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/3//1HDXN///wE)

Answer (score 8):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 12 bytes

```
Retina
.
$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKwjM4NLjUon//x8A)

#### Explanation

```
Retina
```

Initialise the string to `Retina`.

```
.
$_
```

Replace each character with the full string.

Answer (score 8):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 17 bytes

```
/i/\\\//iiiiiiiii
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz9TPyYmRl8/Ewb@/wcA)

(this prints `/////////`)

---

Naive solution is (only) 1 byte longer.

```
\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
```

Trying to remove the duplicated `i`s actually increases byte count.

```
/#/iii//i/\\\//###
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Verbosity](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Verbosity), <s>458</s> 454 bytes

```
Include<Integer>
Include<MetaFunctions>
Include<Output>
Include<String>
Integer:DefineVariable<o; 1>
Output:DefineVariable<P; 0>
String:DefineVariable<s; "VerbosityVerbosityVerbosityVerbosityVerbosityVerbosityVerbosityVerbosityVerbosity">
String:DefineVariable<q; String:RemoveCharactersFromStart<s; o>>
String:DefineVariable<r; String:TakeFirstCharacters<q; o>>
Output:DisplayAsText<P; r>
DefineMain<> [
MetaFunctions:ExecuteScript<MetaFunctions@FILE>
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHBbsIwDIbveYqIJxhXWkWgjUqVhphWxGXawWSGWZSkcxwET1@WdV0FErfdbP/6P1u/j8gbH0jObVs6W8cPzEsnuEM2qh8sUKCIzgp5F4bxMkoTZegrYXK71P/4J0@4JYdrYIJNjbnP9NioznSrvWT6wagOcKuFTI/W/ZX/VYzubfvK9K/wigd/xMdPYLCCHAr2h0qAJV3kzT0A/wFWsMeCOMjASPhk7VOg0NRwnoUVniSF8B16h1sAudzoN3WV/WR@QhsFK8vUyPVfpkX5PDfqvW0v)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to NieDzejkob!

You know your language is verbose when it's shorter to create an 81 character long string that it is to multiply a 9 character long string by 9.

Comment: [454 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZHBbsIwDIbveYqIJxhXWkWgjUqVhphWxGXawWSGWZSkcxwET1@WdV0FErfdbP/6P1u/j8gbH0jObVs6W8cPzEsnuEM2qh8sUKCIzgp5F4bxMkoTZegrYXK71P/4J0@4JYdrYIJNjbnP9NioznSrvWT6wagOcKuFTI/W/ZX/VYzubfvK9K/wigd/xMdPYLCCHAr2h0qAJV3kzT0A/wFWsMeCOMjASPhk7VOg0NRwnoUVniSF8B16h1sAudzoN3WV/WR@QhsFK8vUyPVfpkX5PDfqvW0v)

Comment: @NieDzejkob Nice! That's quite clever!

Answer (score 7):

## [Chef](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Acme-Chef/), 268 bytes

```
C.

Ingredients.
102 l f
101 l e
104 l h
67 l c
4 g i

Method.
Put f into the mixing bowl.
Put e into the mixing bowl.
Put h into the mixing bowl.
Put c into the mixing bowl.
V the i.
Pour contents of the mixing bowl into the baking dish.
V the i until ved.

Serves 1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BCsIwEEX3c4p/gmCl6AFcuRAEwb1NJs1gTaBNq7ePUwUFwa4e/Pc/zNjAvpSdIdrHtmcnHPNgqFqt0cErKyUra2WgzVZhqUYLITpwDskZOo4ZHhJzQg6MmzwktmjSvXs7XnBhwdk/7vyKREtp7GFTzPPVSP63@t03l@scOhnCZ48xZukwsb5AJ@4nHlCZUp4)

#### More idiomatic (565 bytes):

```
PPCG Holiday Punch.

Ingredients.
408 ml apple cider
404 ml ginger beer
416 ml champagne
67 ml unsweetened cranberry juice
4 pinches mixed spice

Method.
Put apple cider into the mixing bowl.
Divide mixed spice into the mixing bowl.
Put ginger beer into the mixing bowl.
Divide mixed spice into the mixing bowl.
Put champagne into the mixing bowl.
Divide mixed spice into the mixing bowl.
Put unsweetened cranberry juice into the mixing bowl.
Sift the mixed spice.
Pour contents of the mixing bowl into the baking dish.
Sift the mixed spice until sifted.

Serves 5.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZFNTsQwDEb3OYVPUIFUBvYgAQukSnOCNHEbQ@pE@ZlhTl@cxUCFGFazzLPzPic2Dqd1HYbHZ3gJnqw@wVDZuE6pV54TWkIuuVP9zQMsHnSMHsGQxSSob2gmnjHBiA3d7hoyTi9Rz4xqd9/OlfMRsSCjBZM0j5jSCd4rGVQ9RJI8zLDQp9RzbFS9YXHBdmqoZRsKxCVAcdi6JRjGcPSdeqKDVLeGC41Ntxn4Grrvx15D9s9PXbi1p6mc6TlAXKEmMIFL2x6E6fe9H9moPxq0lN3fMpmpkIcsJZSFqD2mg2zrrlvXLw)

Comment: Now **that** is a neat language.

Answer (score 6):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 107 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
TALK TO THE HAND "ArnoldCArnoldCArnoldCArnoldCArnoldCArnoldCArnoldC"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzKy89JSf7/3zNEPVgh2MM/PMTT15UrxNHHWyHEXyHEw1XBw9HPRUHJEazQmXhKiSvSPxSoOcxVwcnV1U8hxDXI19PPMcTV5f9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 17 bytes

```python
print("Python"*6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQykAzFfSMtP8/x8A)

Of course, Python 2 is 2 bytes shorter with

```python
print"Python"*6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKQDMVdIy@/8fAA)

But I prefer Python 3

Comment: You know you could have used Python 2...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Edited in, but I prefer Python 3

Comment: Everybody does, but Python 2 is almost always golfier. :P

Comment: @totallyhuman `s/almost/almost\{when manipulating sets and lists}/` :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You missed a terminating `/`?

Comment: Wouldn't `'Python'*6` work too?

Comment: @GalenNare No. The result has to be printed/returned, which that doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

## [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 36 bytes

```
> "Whispers"
> 8
>> 1×2
>> Output 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/99OQSkcylHislOw4LKzUzA8PN0IRPuXlhSUligY//8PAA)

Trivial question, trivial answers.

Comment: A tiny bit more interesting, but same bytecount: https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/99OQSkcylHisrNTcE1MzlAwVDAEsf1LSwpKSxSM/v8HAA

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish),  <s>23 19 15 13</s>  12 bytes

```
"><>" |o<.0l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nOxk5JoSbfRs8g5/9/AA)

[Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) saved 4 bytes. [Not a tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66104/not-a-tree) saved another 3. [Teal pelican](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62009/teal-pelican) managed to save 1 more byte. Thanks to all who have helped golfing! Citing Arnauld, with slight modifications: *I now have 15 seconds of experience in ><> programming. So, this may actually be golfable*.

Comment: `"><>><>><>"oa0.`

Comment: 13 bytes: `"><>"|o<"><>"`

Comment: After having a play around using both Emigna and Notatree's changes and mixing both you can reduce this a further 1 byte:    "><>" |o<.0l

Comment: @Tealpelican: That is ingenious!

Comment: @Tealpelican Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide an explanation?

Comment: @FlipTack Not sure I completely understand my code, but: `"><>" ` enables string parsing and pushes ><> to the stack, `|` mirrors (the IP will change direction depending on what direction it already has), `o` outputs as a character (string, in this case), `<` changes the direction of the instruction to the left, `.` pops the last two elements off the stack and moves the IP to the point which has the two as coordinates, `0` just pushes a `0` and `l` pushes the length of the stack onto the stack. If you dunno what I mean by "IP" and "direction", please see [this](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I understand 2D languages, I just wasn't aware of the specific command `.`

Answer (score 5):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 6 bytes

```
',9i×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU0sSfz/X13HMvPw9P//AQ)

Hehe...

Answer (score 5):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 3 bytes

```
31317403
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M///39jQ2NDcxMD4/38A)

Format similar to Hello World program, except output mode is `3` (Byte-per-three-commands). The three commands `131` encodes value `131` base 6 = `37` base 16 = character 7. Then `3` prints the character.

Answer (score 5):

## [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 146 bytes

```
        + +*`        + +  * +  *       +* .                + +  * +          + * + .       + * +          + +* +  *        + * . . . .      + * +'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fAQq0FbS1EpA4CgpaEAIqoqWgp4AGEKoQIiCuHgoPWTmKkWB5PShEaFD//x8A)

It looks prettier with decoration, though (180 bytes):

```
        + +*`        
+ + /| * +  *       +
* .| \__             
  + \__/+  * +__     
     + * + . /  \    
+ * +      ========  
  + +* +  *  \__/    
  + * . . . .      + 
* +'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5LCsAwCET3nmJ2hQjJCXqTQNorpN0UcnerYVI6guLv6XWfvT9moBSajpWIZygDyYM7TkhCHqit4S@JXS@WOarsCqFByChAJXciQztFgq5bgfq4fpFGnv@gm9kL)

Answer (score 4):

## [Commentator](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Commentator), 316 bytes

```
           {-     {-    -}!  {-{- e#-}//{-#-}-}! {-       
;{-
     {-   -}!!  -}////{-#{-#-}    {-     -}!-}//-}//e#   e#-}//     -}//-}//{-e#                   e#-}-}//e#      e#-}//-}//-}//-}//e#         e#{-e# e#{-e# e#{-e#         e#-}-}-}-}-}
;{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*{-/*-}-}-}-}-}-}-}-}-}-}-}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU4xDoAwCNz7ijbdTAgP8DXGMKqJ6UZ8ewXaWHQScqVw3LXrsW20l6UcZ61xBIMrcCW9SkMZLkQGKTrsWzGGmSEMhXBJT0Rbtn3nKrRyCsrSN9dOtTmDMd8ge7jLHqWHk1E2l3d5O7XU3@P0F0Pns9Yb)

Not quite as long as my Verbosity answer, but getting there

Answer (score 3):

### [MSM](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MSM), 9 bytes

```
..;;..MSM
```

Stack trace:

```
. . ; ; . . M S M             -- concat
  . ; ; . . M MS              -- concat
    ; ; . . MSM               -- dup
      ; . . MSM MSM           -- dup
        . . MSM MSM MSM       -- concat
          . MSM MSMMSM        -- concat
            MSMMSMMSM
```

Answer (score 3):

## D, 20 bytes

```
auto f(){return"D";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/mfmVuQX1SiUFySogfEmfnW/xNLS/IV0jQ0q4tSS0qL8pRclKxr/5flZ6Yo5CZm5mloclVzKQBBeVFmSaoGUJ2mNVftfwA)

Comment: One letter language names for the win.

Answer (score 3):

## [I](https://github.com/mlochbaum/ILanguage), 3 bytes

```
"I"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/z/X8lT6f9/AA)

Comment: Haha I got ninja'd

Answer (score 3):

## [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji), 33 bytes

```
Emoji6➡
```

Abuses the type system. A lot. May not work on other interpreters than the Python one. It probably won't.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///D/ElrXEFMEAOEzSCMyUs/zJ@46tG8hf//AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 16 bytes

```
o"pp
tkpp
ecp
"A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//z9fqaCAqyQbSKQmF3ApOf7/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 16 bytes

```
print("Funky"*5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/7@gKDOvREPJDcRT0jLV/P8fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
•äƵí•h6×R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOiw0uObT28FsjIMDs8Pej/fwA)

---

0xE1BA50, encoded in base 255, decoded into hexadecimal, repeated 6 times, reversed.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
4ç"Japt
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NOciSmFwdA==&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [;#*](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/SemicolonHashStar), 420 bytes

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K84o@P/fmnygTCU15KgdUW75/x8A) (uses ;#+ instead)

Comment: You can golf this approach.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Well I intended this to be a ;# answer but since that is not considered a language (it cannot perform a primality test), I used ;#+. Will look at the docs and see what I can do

Comment: This is a kolgomorov complexity challenge, so primality testing isn't required. This can be a `;#` answer if you still want to

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Changed to ;#*

Answer (score 2):

## [K](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 9 bytes

```
\echo "K"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P8/JjU5I19ByVvp/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 27 bytes

```
1FORI=1TO6:?"uBASIC";:NEXTI
```

This answer is pretty small, thanks to uBASIC's tokenizer being powered with a solution of magic in unicorn blood.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/f0M0/yNPWMMTfzMpeqdTJMdjTWcnays81IsTz/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 10 bytes

```
isedsedsed
```

I hope two trailing newlines are OK :P

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/P7M4NQWC/v8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [itflabtijtslwi](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Itflabtijtslwi), 31 bytes

```perl
/I/itflabtijtslwi//J/IIIIIII/JJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BS8NAEIXv/RVdWOhOKR0ieHEbimING4ogBjy4banNtl1ZbcgsFInxr8clEYRanMM7zLz3zStM6S4bvoonk8Hs/nalsrv59U2m0uxx/qQGcrM/FLJBhdZv3frF21dP7mgRU1TdYJo2f5O94946IyKo7FYQWyaJENOr5yVqvfjUegzDKSQJYwTV20ePU8wjGfSLgkGMAXmEO5I8j3fGbwTIDkcYIPqBk54FS45Q1bVx1L0QHb3VZDEExvqHsh8OLbF9VZT23QsegfyN4WkxOLP5KSo4jXgOcUCM@AWcb3yy@be5qdyavKzr5hs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ovs*

```
00000000: 732a 4d4a ca49 4d2f cda5 1603 00         s*MJ.IM/.....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypNSspJTS/N/f/fAAqsFMyNjRIVTFJMEhWSE00sgSyjNIXklERTBUMzA2MFAwMFGCjW8vXS8/TV1wOB//8B)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypNSspJTS/N/f/fAAqsFMyNjRIVTFJMEhWSE00sgSyjNIXklERTBUMzA2MFAwMFGCjW8vXS8/TV1wOB//8B), generated with [zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli).

Comment: @ovs Thanks! I was pretty sure I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Hexadecimal-Stacking-Pseudo-Assembly-Language), 636 bytes

```
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
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJNCgMhDIWvFGMcx2WheI922qGLLgq9P7ZRYd5AkoV8PJ75I6/v5/ZujYmIr0I510p0@YcqSxLS6JyBw8HZ8zxtv2wHM0GeAn7wLAz8AIa6OdosUJfx7w4szixO/kR2/@7sONcdODr7hH5SdGpt9t/TfopTK9mzn3pYbb9MfViF9VqESqmVp9wVVmUwD8909uuK/dUMgYJeWms/)

Formatted:

```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```

### Explanation

```
; initialize 77 with 0x002D (45)
20 002D
40 77 (FF)

; label AAAA
00 AAAA

; print out the text
20006540000020006740000020006140000020007540000020006740000020006e40000020006140000020004c400000200020400000
20007940000020006c40000020006240000020006d40000020006540000020007340000020007340000020004140000020002d400000
20006f40000020006440000020007540000020006540000020007340000020005040000020002040000020006740000020006e400000
20006940000020006b40000020006340000020006140000020007440000020005340000020002040000020006c400000200061400000
20006d400000200069400000200063400000200065400000200064400000200061400000200078400000200065400000200048400000
140000

; decrement
    ; move counter to stack 99
        42 77 (FF)
        40 99 (FF)
    ; push 1 to 77
        20 0001
        40 77 (FF)
    ; move counter to stack 77
        42 99 (FF)
        40 77 (FF)
    ; subtract
        22 77 (FF)

; duplicate
42 77 (FF)
40 77 (FF)

; terminate if counter is 0
03 77 (FF)
04 (0001)

; redo
01 AAAA
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 46 bytes

```ml
val s="Standard ML";s^s^s;print(it^it^it^s^s);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/@/LDFHodhWKbgkMS8lsShFwddHybo4DgitC4oy80o0MkviIAgopGn9/z8A)

#### Output:

```ml
Standard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard MLStandard ML
```

---

#### Previous version: (55 bytes)

```ml
"Standard ML";print(concat(map(fn _=>it)(explode it)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/9fKbgkMS8lsShFwddHybqgKDOvRCM5Py85sUQjN7FAIy1PId7WLrNEUyO1oiAnPyVVAcjW1LT@/x8A) (No worries, the code is harmless, eventhough it contains `explode it`.)

#### Explanation:

`"Standard ML";` binds the string to the implicit value identifier `it`. We then `explode it` to convert the string into a list of characters and `map` a function `fn _=>it` over the list which replaces each character with the string. `concat` combines the list of strings to a single string and `print` outputs the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 38 bytes

```
hodor.hod("HodorHodorHodorHodorHodor")
```

It's actually shorter than the pure Javascript equivalent!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8hPyS/6/z8DROkBSQ0lDxATG6Gk@f8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 11, 19 bytes

```java
v->"Java".repeat(4)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY0xCsMwDEX3nkJksod46hbaAxSapZCldFAdtzh1lBArhlJydlchAWnQ1@P9DhOWXfvJNmCMcEVPvwOAJ3bTC62Dej0Bbjx5eoNVzeBbSLqSdJGViYzsLdRAcIKcynNxEWlhJjc6ZHXUudrAcX4GAXc@raJe@tTmvj9Q713fyK43w8xmlA8HUmSsojkEvRcv@Q8)

## Java 8, 21 bytes

```java
v->"JavaJavaJavaJava"
```

Well...

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##TY0xCsMwDEX3nkJksofkAqE9QKFZCl1CB9Vxi1NHCbFiKCVndxXioaA/6Ovr/R4jluNkqe/eyXgMAS7o6HsAcMR2fqKx0GwrwJVnRy8w6ja6DqKuxV1FMoGRnYEGCI6QYnkqzgL@V5HqPTotDy/R/BE31CCNaqe3d9S57RPYDtW4cDXJhT0pqoyixXudq9f0Aw)

Comment: [JAVA! JAVA! JAVA! JAVA!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IszLs.gif)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>125</s> 119 bytes

```
+++++++++[>+++++++++++[>+++++++++[>+>+<<-]>>+<<<-]>>-.>++++.<-.++++++++.>----.<---.>+++++++.<---.++++++++.>[-]<[-]<<<-]
```

First BF, I think it's still golfable but it may be a bit BF to golf BF ;)

Explanation:

```
+++++++++                        (_009  000  000  000  000)
[
 >+++++++++++                    ( 009 _011  000  000  000)
 [
  >+++++++++                     ( 009  011 _009  000  000)
  [
   >+>+<<-                       ( 009  011 _008  001  001)
  ]                              ( 009  011 _000  009  009)
  >>+<<<-                        ( 009 _010  000  009  010)
 ]                               ( 009 _000  000  099  110)
 >>-.                            ( 009  000  000 _098  110) Output: b
 >++++.                          ( 009  000  000  098  114) Output: r
 <-.                             ( 009  000  000 _097  114) Output: a
 ++++++++.                       ( 009  000  000 _105  114) Output: i
 >----.                          ( 009  000  000  105 _110) Output: n
 <---.                           ( 009  000  000 _102  110) Output: f
 >+++++++.                       ( 009  000  000  102 _117) Output: u
 <---.                           ( 009  000  000 _099  117) Output: c
 ++++++++.                       ( 009  000  000 _107  117) Output: k
 >[-]<[-]<<<-                    (_008  000  000  000  000)
]                                (_000  000  000  000  000)
```

-6 for removing redundant clear commands

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwai7bS1sXGATDttGxvdWDsQBaZ19cDSeja6ejBVena6QAAU0YVKQuR1kVVE68bagDDIkP//AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, ~33 tokenized BASIC bytes for the listing

```
 LET A$="BASIC"
 1 FOR I=SGN PI TO LEN A$
 2 PRINT A$;
 3 NEXT I
```

Enter the language name into the `var stack` using direct mode to save one BASIC line, and save bytes in the listing itself. I assume the `A$` variable is five bytes for the string and two bytes for the pointer, but I'm not 100% sure how the this works on the `ZX81` - I will find out and update the byte count.

#### Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC (non-dynamic solution) ~21 tokenized BASIC bytes (symbolic listing)

```
 LET A$="BASIC"
 1 PRINT A$;A$;A$;A$;A$
```

Using the same technique as above, entering the `A$` variable in direct mode and then simply printing the string five times. To run either solution, don't use the command `RUN` or the `var stack` is initialised. Use:

```
 GOTO 1
```

Comment: Save 5 bytes by using `SGN PI` instead of `1`. And by my count the second one is only 36 bytes.

Comment: Yes, I will optimise futher; also one could use `INPUT A$` in line one, and will therefore work with any language inputted into the `A$` string

Comment: @Neil - how are you counting 36 bytes in the second listing?

Comment: The first line is 4 bytes for the line number and length, 1 for the token, 10 normal bytes, 1 for the newline. The second is similar, except it has 14 normal bytes. I make that 36 bytes in total.

Comment: It's a good job I put a ~ in front of my byte count isn't it. Somehow I mis-counted. Twice. But I'd rather work out proper byte counts on 8 bit machines, i.e., how much actual memories do my listings take?

Comment: Hi `MD XF` - the Sinclair ZX81 is just that - I've never seen it referred to as a `ZX-81`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (9 bytes)

```
PHPPHPPHP
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be566543825e75a8f503dbd2f38f2d0f0a706de3)

Comment: Hah. can't believe `str_repeat(3,'PHP')` is the long alternative.

Comment: Excuse my brevity with this answer; it's hardly a difficult challenge and by the questions posed above, it's apparently a perfectly legal one as well.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 16 bytes

```
"TI-BASIC
Disp Ans,Ans
Ans
```

Alternatively (19 bytes):

```
For(I,1,3
Disp "TI-BASIC
End
```

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, 27 Bytes

Edit: Much cleaner solution <s>of the same length</s> suggested by [James Holderness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62101/james-holderness)

```
0"39-egnufeB">:#,_$1+:9`#@_
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30DJ2FI3NT2vNC3VScnOSlknXsVQ28oyQdkh/v9/AA)

Old 30 byte version:

```
?
_g7-00p"39-egnufeB">:#,_g`#@
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/354rPt1S18CgQCk1Pa80LdVJyc5KWSc@PUHZ4f9/AA)

It feels weird to use the ? command for something that isn’t random, but that’s the only direction changing instruction that had an ASCII value low enough

Comment: Surely it's easier to just keep the counter on the stack: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30ApNT2vNC3VScnOSlknXsVQ28osQdkh/v9/AA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JamesHolderness Not if you're printing the "-93" as well. Then it's the same length (but still a much cleaner solution)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 14 bytes

```
echo bash{,,,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hCcis1tHRqf3/HwA)

## ksh, 12 bytes

```
echo ksh{,,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P8/NTkjXyG7OKNaR6f2/38A)

## sh, 10 bytes

```
echo sh{,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzhDQTdZQSk1OSNfoTijWqdW6f9/AA)

Although, for 9 bytes, I can just do `echo shsh`.

Answer (score 2):

## Underload, 28 bytes

```
(Underload)::::::::********S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fIxTG1rSCAi0oCP7/HwA)

Comment: `(Underload)::**::**S` for 20 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
“¢³ƒ»ẋ5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9qZWxsef//4oCcwqLCs8aSwrvhuos1//8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 11 bytes

```
L,"Add++"5*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR8kxJUVbW8lU6/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.herokuapp.com), 7 bytes

```
*4"Pyth
```

My first Pyth answer!

Thanks to Mr. Xcoder for a neat trick.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8tEKQDMAAA)

Comment: `*4"Pyth` for 7 bytes

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, neat!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>27</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

First PHP solution; thanks to everyone who helped out with this. Obviously, I'm not quite ready to start golfing in PHP yet!

```
<?=str_pad(P,9,HPP);
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKQoviAxRSNAx1LHIyBA0/r/fwA)

(Yes, `<?="PHPPHPPHP";` or just `PHPPHPPHP` are shorter but they felt *far* too trivial.)

- Thanks to Dennis for some tips on PHP, which also saved a byte.
- Thanks to NieDzejkob for saving a further 5 bytes.
- Thanks to Titus for saving me a byte and teaching me something new abut PHP.

Comment: This looks longer than just using `"PHPPHPPHP"` to me.

Comment: @MartinEnder: yeah, but that just felt far too trivial!

Comment: A trailing semicolon is mandatory in PHP. As a full program [`<?=str_pad($s="PHP",9,$s);`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKQoviAxRUOl2FYpwCNAScdSR6VY0/r/fwA "PHP – Try It Online") would do. Of course, [`PHPPHPPHP`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/wCMAgv7/BwA "PHP – Try It Online") is a neat 9 byte solution.

Comment: @Dennis, to the best of my knowledge, a trailing semi-colon isn't required on the last line of a file. Thanks for the tips on the full programme; I'll update shortly.

Comment: It can be omitted in certain situations, but the closing `?>` is already longer.

Comment: @Dennis, ah, yes, I see that now.

Comment: [`<?=str_pad("",9,PHP);`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKQoviAxRUNJScdSJ8AjQNP6/38A) for 21 bytes.

Comment: Or getting closer to the trivial solution for 18 bytes: [`<?=($a=PHP).$a.$a;`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WQyXRNsAjQFNPJRGIrP//BwA)

Comment: Oops, fell asleep on the couch yesterday and forgot about this! Thanks for the help, everyone; clearly I'm not ready for golfing in PHP yet! :D

Comment: 20 bytes: `<?=str_pad(P,9,HPP);`

Comment: Can you explain, @Titus? How come the `P` & `HPP` don't need to be quoted?

Comment: @Shaggy you don't need to quote strings in PHP as long as you ignore the errors (if there isn't any space or special chars such as `-` or `$` in your string). It's actually [one of the top PHP golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2916)

Comment: @Shaggy and with `-n` (which we get for free: no config file), notices such as `undefined constant, assuming string` are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

## APL,  <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
∊(⍴c)⍴⊂c←⎕

APL => APLAPLAPL
```

previous answer above prompted for screen input but if no input is required then we have the trivial for 7 bytes

```
9⍴'APL'
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++,  <s>24</s>  22 bytes

*Thanks to @Quentin for saving two bytes!*

```
[]{return"C++C++C++";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6vnJmXnFOakqpgk5lfXFKUmphrx5WZV6KQm5iZp6HJVc2lAASJpSX5Cmm2Mf@jY6uLUktKi/KUnLW1IUjJuvY/SI11cUmKlVVyfmmJgo2NQpqGpjVX7X8A)

Comment: You can drop the parentheses :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
‼D¨Ż%k
```

-2 bytes thanks to @Zgarb!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDHpdDK47uVgWyAQ) or alternatively [`DD¨Ż%k`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/38Xl0Iqju1WBLAA) would work too..

#### Explanation

```
‼D¨Ż%k
  ¨Ż%k  -- compressed string: "Husk"
‼D      -- duplicate twice: "HuskHuskHuskHusk"
```

Comment: `‼D` works too.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 30 bytes

```
 OUTPUT =DUPL('SNOBOL4',7)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/X8E/NCQgNETB1iU0wEdDPdjP38nfx0Rdx1yTy9XP5f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 11 bytes

```
'Deorst'l6*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f9f3QXMUM8x0/r/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 59 bytes

Not the best way to do it (and there's a better php solution), but here's my go at it:

```
<?php $s="php";$l=strlen($s);for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++){echo $s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBpdhWCUgrWavk2BaXFOWk5mmoFGtap@UXaahk2hpYq2TaqOQASW1tzerU5Ix8oAbr2v//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [rk](https://github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang), 22 bytes

```
rk:start
print: "rkrk"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8r@/78o26q4JLGohKugKDOvxEpBqSi7KFvp/38A)

Comment: Wait someone else knows about this language :o

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 26 bytes

```matlab
disp(repmat('Octave',1,6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QKMotSA3sURD3R8sqK5jqGOmqfn/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 33 bytes

```
for x=1 to 8
print"MY-BASIC"
next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z8tv0ihwtZQoSRfwYKroCgzr0TJN1LXyTHY01mJKy@1ouT/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
"05AB1E"6×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fycDU0cnQVcns8PT//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 22 bytes

```
7v
"<_@#:-1,k6"Befunge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/37yMS8km3kHZStdQJ9tMyQki9f8/AA)

with `-98` included:

```
av
"<_@#:-1,k9"Befunge-98
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/P7GMS8km3kHZStdQJ9tSyQlJCgA)

Comment: -2 bytes if you [increment instead of decrementing](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/Xyk1Pa80LdVJySxbx1DbyixB2SH@/38A) (idea from james holderness' comment on my Befunge-93 answer)

Answer (score 1):

## [pl](https://github.com/quartata/pl-lang), 4 bytes

```
plpl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8j5/78gpwBIAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy), 12 bytes

```
"CyCy" print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S678/1/JudK5UkmhoCgzr@T/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>49</s> 37 bytes

*12 bytes saved thanks to @cliffroot*

```clj
(print(apply str(repeat 7"Clojure")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X6OgKDOvRCOxoCCnUqG4pEijKLUgNbFEwVzJGaJESVNT8/9/AA)

Comment: you can use `apply str` instead of `clojure.string/join` ?

Comment: @cliffroot nice trick. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>14</s>  12 bytes

```perl6
say 'Perl6'x 5
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBPQDEVq9QMP3/HwA)

```perl6
{'Perl6'x 5}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X5xYqZCS/79aPQDEVa9QMK39/x8A) <sup><sub>(bare block lambda that returns a string)</sub></sup>

Note that I have it output `Perl6` as *Perl 5* and *Perl 6* are at least as different as *C++* and *Java* are.

Comment: try this `{'Perl'x 5}` to shave off 3 bytes :) Lambda returns are generally accepted as output. Also the question specifically says that different versions of a language, dosent matter. And since it is code golf, i wouldve used that in my favor ;)

Comment: @HåvardNygård As I stated Perl 5 and Perl 6 are different languages; they are significantly more different than `C` and `C++`, and the `C++` answer outputs `C++C++C++`. At least Perl 5 attempts to maintain backwards compatibility with the original Perl from 1987. I have written an example file that combines both Perl 5 and Perl 6, and the code that I have written to make them compatible is larger than the common code. The language is Perl 6, the family of languages is Perl.

Comment: Well, could still return it from the lambda though

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 14 bytes

```
puts TclTclTcl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCEkOQeC/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
×Charcoal⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///wdGco@1Hjjv//AQ) Alternatively, also 10 bytes:

```
×⁸Charcoal
Ｆ⁸Charcoal
```

More idiomatic for 13 bytes would be to say:

```
≔Charcoalθ⭆θθ
≔CharcoalθＦθθ
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 29 bytes

```
c="CleanCleanCleanCleanClean"
```

Because actually doing anything requires `import StdEnv`, it's shorter to just hardcode.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3P9lWyRkkiI1Q@h9cklhUomCrkPz/X3JaTmJ68X9dT5//LpV5ibmZycUA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES7, 30/41/43/33 bytes

Thanks @Shaggy for reducing the size of the second and 4th versions

#### Boring repeat 10 times: 30 bytes

```js
alert("JavaScript".repeat(10))
```

#### Array mapping of a string: 41 bytes

```js
alert([...x="JavaScript"].fill(x).join``)
```

#### For loop: 43 bytes

```js
for(i=j='';10>j++;i+="JavaScript");alert(i)
```

#### Joining empty 11 element array: 33 bytes

```js
alert(Array(11).join`JavaScript`)
```

Comment: From the spec "*Use the common name or acronym of the language.*" - JS is a common acronym for JavaScript ;)

Comment: Also, your last solution can be 33 bytes: `alert(Array(11).join'JavaScript')`, replacing single quotes with backticks.

Comment: And your second can be 41 bytes: `alert([...x="JavaScript"].fill(x).join'')`.

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 17 bytes

```
a/ReRegex/aaaaaaa
```

Potentially one of the most simple ReRegex answers I've ever written.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/P1E/KDUIxNRPhID//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 20 bytes

```
main(){printf("C");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8lZSdO69v9/AA)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using `puts` instead

Comment: And even more by making it a function, `f(){puts("C");}`

Answer (score 1):

### [This=That](https://esolangs.org/wiki/This%3DThat), 57 bytes

```
a=This=That
i=0
while loop j=<9
a=print
while loop j=end
```

This does exactly what you think it does. The string stored to `a` is printed nine times, accomplished by the loop.

The idea I get from the Esolangs page is that that equals sign in the first line is part of the string literal, not an assignment operator.

Thanks to @FrownyFrog for pointing out an error.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 15 bytes

#### `xxd`-style hexdump:

```
00000000: 53d0 80a3 8100 2080 b525 3dc2 e5e1 6e    SÐ.£.. .µ%=Âåán
```

#### JavaScript equivalent:

```
'Bean'.repeat(4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNzPv/3wAKrBRMjVMMFCwMEo0VLAwNDBSMDCwMFJJMjUwVjFOSjRRSTVMNFcxSFYAg@PAEvUOL9fQU9A5tVbU93HR46eGFQJMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
$><<"Ruby"*4
```

Because Kaiser Chiefs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkYpCMhU0jL5X1BaUqygpOCYkZiomwgj9JQUtIGCLvkKlfmlCiBlAA)

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL, <s>76</s> 67 bytes

```
declare @i char(5)='T-SQL',@ int=1 a:print @i set @+=1if(@<6)goto a
```

Comment: You can save up to 11 bytes by using `@i+=1` instead of `@i=@i+1`, change the condition to `@i<6`, swapping the variable names and replacing the `WHILE` with a `GOTO `and `IF`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Decimal](//git.io/Decimal), 52 bytes

```
13068101099105109097108D117D91D00D30101D111D42D591D5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYmxDYAwEMRWOhNC8v0tgoAiEuxfPl9Ztu/nWt/5ZtJ0TIQiUC8oBpqG4cCSW03K8b65V@uZPw)

Ungolfed / explanation:

```
13068101099105109097108D 117D   ; push "Decimal", push 17
91D                             ; create jump point 1
  00D 301 01D                   ; set DSI to 0 ("Bitwise"), print, set back to 1 (initially 7)
  111D 42D                      ; push 1, subtract from previous SI
5 91D 5                         ; if DSI truthy, jump to point 1
```

Fun fact that I just remembered: Decimal doesn't care about the "top of stack" like most stack-based esolangs; it instead operates on a "default stack index" that can be modified at will, allowing for rather easy stack manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 229 bytes

```
((()()()()()){}){({}<(((((((((((((()()()){}){}()){}){}()){}()))<({}[(()()()()()){}])>())[(()()()){}])<(((((()()()()())){}{})){}{})>(()()()()){})[()()()()()])[(()()()()){}])((()()()()){}){}())(((((()()()()){}){}){}()){})>[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsAwCAS/sx7yAwn0HZJDeiiUlh56DXm7tQltooIL6zK63nm/wnbmQxUAfU2lUkGpDFdjV53aILa4eESiaCqYDJ5AzTTXOH1GzPdlpBIJHBcu2R5w4O7@b0Z5GXZCVcPyAA)

This is 228 bytes of code, and `+1` for the `-A` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala <strike>27</strike> 16 bytes

```
print("Scala"*5)
```

Comment: I don't know Scala, but would assigning it to a variable be shorter than writing it twice?

Comment: or just using `5` instead of `"Scala".size`

Comment: Assigning to a variable takes 29 bytes unfortunately. And yes @Giuseppe I'm dumb....

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 10 bytes

```
p "ruby"*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBqQjIUNIy@f8fAA)

Comment: `p"ruby"*4` - you don't need the space.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript <strike>58</strike> 54 bytes

```
a='',f=i=>i<9?(f(i+1),a+="JavaScript"):0;f(0);alert(a)
```

### Solution using `document.write` (<strike>57</strike> 53 bytes)

```
(f=i=>{i<9?f(i+1):0;document.write("JavaScript")})(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Please edit your existing answers instead of posting new ones.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 22 Byte

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?[Rept("Excel VBA",9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 30 bytes

```swift
for _ in 1...5{print("Swift")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/Lb9IIV4hM0/BUE9Pz7S6oCgzr0RDKRgkq6RZ@/8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bitwise](//github.com/aaronryank/bitwise), 188 bytes

```
.SUB:
LABEL &1
NOT $1 *1
AND *1 $2 *2
XOR $1 $2 $1
SL *2 &1 $2
JMP @1 $2
RET $1
MOV 1 &7 &1
OUT &66 1
OUT &105 1
OUT &116 1
OUT &119 1
OUT &105 1
OUT &115 1
OUT &101 1
SUB 1 &1 1
JMP &-9 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osKc8sTv3/Xy841MmKy8fRydVHQc2Qy88/REHFUEHLkMvRzwVIKagYKWgZcUX4B4GEgRwVQ65gH6AQUDGQy@XlG6DgAGYFuYJ0cvn6hykYKqiZgwzzDw1RUDMzU4CyDA1M4UxDhKihJVYFCKaBIZAJdCbIXBATZKeaLlDX//8A)

I can't golf the `.SUB` help D:

Answer (score 0):

## C# Interactive, 44 bytes

```
for(int i=15;--i>0;)Write("C# Interactive");
```

Haven't found an online compiler, I did it with the C# Interactive REPL in VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
Implicit":+7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/98TyM5MzixRstI2//8fAA)

```
Implicit       push character codes for I, m, p, l, i, c, i, t
        "      stringify stack
         :     duplicate top of stack
          +7   concatenate top of stack to previous 7 times
               implicit string output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel Formula, 24

```
=REPT("ExcelFormula",12)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//git.io/shortC), 24 bytes

```
Da"shortC"
AJa a a a a a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fJVGpGMR0VuJy9EpUgMP//wE)

```
Da"shortC"     // define variable a as string "shortC"
A              // main function
 J             // print string
  a a a a a a  // a, 6 times, auto-concatenated
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <s>24</s> 15 bytes

Minus 9 bytes thanks to SalchiPapa

```julia
print("Julia"^5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/7@gKDOvRKMotSA1sURDKQskqKRjqqn5/z8A)

Comment: `print("Julia"^5)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Eukleides](http://www.eukleides.org/), 37 bytes

```
e="Eukleides"
print e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e
```

Don't think it can be golfed down any further. While a list of strings can be printed, they can't be assigned to a variable without a `cat` operation. So, building a string of three "Eukleides"es and printing three of those blows up to 38 bytes:

```
e="Eukleides"
f=cat(e,e,e)
print f,f,f
```

Eukleides prints a newline after every `print` command. If the challenge allowed for newlines between instances of the language name then we could do this in 33 bytes:

```
for i=1to 9
print "Eukleides"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 11 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?"VBAVBAVBA
```

Answer (score 0):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 75 bytes

```
HAI 1.3
VISIBLE "LOLCODELOLCODELOLCODELOLCODELOLCODELOLCODELOLCODE"
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8FQz5grzDPY08nHVUHJx9/H2d/FlXhKics7xCPCKdL1/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 11 bytes

```
`Pushy\x5`:N"
```

Where `\x5` represents the literal byte `0x05`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z8hAESzJlj5Kf3/DwA)**

```
`Pushy\x5`      \ Push the character codes for 'Pushy', and a 5
          :     \ Pop the 5 and loop 5 times:
           N"   \ Output the rest of the stack, with no newline.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 12 bytes

```
$><<"Ruby"*4
```

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151022/66104 ?

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 83 bytes

For the whole version string:

```bsh
while read -n1;do echo -n `bash --version|head -1`;done< <(bash --version|head -1)
```

Returns (on my machine):

```bsh
GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: `Use the common name or acronym of the language.` and `If there are multiple versions of a language, you need not include the version number.` and for just plain `bash` [I don't think it can get any shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151127/61563) (although I may be wrong.)

Comment: @MDXF You're right, I didn't read the challenge properly.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 15 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes no input and outputs to the calling cell

```
=REPT("Excel",5
```

This may be ported to Google Sheets for 24 Bytes

```
=REPT("Google Sheets",13
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tomato, 14 bytes

```
"Tomato"YYYYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby: 10 chars

```
p 'ruby'*4
```

Result

```
rubyrubyrubyruby
```

## *Previous Implementation: 25 chars*

```
def x(y);p y*y.length;end
```

Simple invocation:

```
x('javascript')
 => "javascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascriptjavascript"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 15 bytes

```
"Powershell"*10
```

Very boring. But I can't think of any way to shorten it.