# Add a egaugnaL to a polyglot

Tags: polyglot, answer-chaining

This is an [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) question, which means that all answers are affected by those before them.

## The task

The *n*-th answer to this question must run in all languages that are present in answers before it. They need not run in order, but must print the name of the language currently running, *reversed*.

### Additional rules

- A language cannot be used twice.
- Your program must run without errors. Using errors to log the language name is not permitted, but you are allowed to use errors to determine language.
- Each answer must be no more than 30% or 40 bytes (whichever is larger) longer than the previous answer. If the percentage is not an integer, it is rounded **down**.
- Your added language must be a [free implementation](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7822/62131) language.
- Any interpreter for a language is allowed.
- If you can link to reproducible results, please do so.
- The name of the language being reversed is Case-insensitive, so '3nohtyp' is valid for Python 3.0
- You may not put 2 answers in a row.
- If your language does not support strings, print the letters as numbers, following this pattern: "A" = 0, "B" = 1, "C" = 2...
- In the case of a language not supporting strings *and* having non-letter characters in its name, print -1 instead of the non-letter character. Please show verification that the language does not support strings.

## Victory condition

If this question goes for 20 days without an answer, the *second to last* answer wins.

## Answer format

> ## 4. CoffeeScript, 20 bytes
>
> ```
> (program goes here)
> ```
>
> This program prints **nohtyp** in Python 3, and **tpircsavaj** in JavaScript.
>
> (If you wish to explain how you did it, do so here)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102370/60043)

Comment: why should programs have to run without error? it seems rather arbitrary

Comment: @ConorO'Brien because that means that it it not a true polyglot - a polyglot is valid in all languages that it is associated with.

Comment: Warning: [This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150870/output-the-language-name-times-the-number-of-characters), which involves the language name, is closed as unclear.

Comment: @user202729 will fix question accordingly.

Comment: What is a languages name?  For example if I had something that worked in OCaml but not other varieties of Caml would the name be OCaml or Caml?  Because OCaml is the name of the implementation, but it is an implementation of Caml.

Comment: @CatWizard I believe it would be the language implementation name.

Comment: Can Language 13 modify what Language 12 prints if the new output still meets the rules?

Comment: How so @NieDzejkob, just changing the case?

Comment: @Zacharý changing the case, or `python3` vs `python 3`... EDIT: or for my COM file answer, there should be many correct variants

Comment: @NieDzejkob I think that would be okay. No drastic changes, though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "need not run in order" part. It implies that it's possible for the "order" to matter in the first place, but it seems to me that it wouldn't.

Comment: Is a trailing newline allowed?

Comment: The rule of alternating answers [is harmful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot#comment406368_102370). 
And now it [is harming](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45539627#45539627) BMO. We all are losing because BMO cannot add an answer, there is nothing good in this situation. 
I think such challenges as this, that build a bigger thing based on previous answers, should not prohibit a user from adding several answers in a row and should not have a winning condition.
This challenge is more a collaboration than a competition.

Comment: @stasoid If it doesn't have a winning criteria, it should be hosted somewhere else tha  PPCG. I would suggest "the second to last **poster** wins", that way you can still enc collaboration, posting multiple answer in a row isn't good for you and it still has a winning criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 49. boolfuck, 3989 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M eliF MOC SODeerF$}++++-+[*///opfzzfzzfzzfzzzfzzfzfzfffzffzzzzzffzfzzzffzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzfffzzfzfzzzfzffff⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 & I8 H I  d      $$$
a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP<
>"gnalokniM"OOOOOOOOO.
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
01 & && &&&     & {}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩+-+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]>+{}[<<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>->-]<+[<<+.<++++++++++++.>>+.<+++.<--.>+.--------.<++++.>+.>>{}]>](()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")+;;+;+;+;+;;+;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;+;+;+;+;;;+;;+;;+;;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;;+;+";x--?y
 =y;y="yrruC";(!)=seq;main=let b!_=""in putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++y--?"lleksaH"
--N'Zi(Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*///∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejzaciiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaceeacewuuuweejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw;+;;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;;+;+;;;+;;+;⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `eliF MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86
- `NOOPS` in Spoon
- `yrruC` in Curry
- `gnalokniM` in Minkolang
- `epyhniarb` in Brainhype
- `kcufloob` in boolfuck

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbchvHlc@cX8hLa0gTMwQGQ5ASRYIAwrskryQyoixpBUDIYNAAhhjMIHMBCNF0uTZVrk3VVuzKg/fysLa3dlN7SbYqrvhha7Mvynv8D/yB5A@053T3XHChJDsZEjPd596nT19OY9A0/O7r14tkt9UiBqEdI@w4xn0SuFAbuPa4Y7sBCagfkK7hOdT3SXNMHlr04CU967lNaZHsu7ZtDHxK5H23RWViOC0i73qdsE@dwJeJT83Ach2ftF2PNGkQUI/Q8wH1LOqYVJJMIyAVYgKvZDtE81mR3fLNNlkke7QdOh2qba3P4Ps9GwgeWE7PtQ2nIwVuaHbJwLNAsQSmWW0ydkNiYNsig3Kkb/Qo8UOPYiv7bstqjwlYmB@Mie@SoAv2BF06BhZKLMe0wxZtQQGBxAZdEjW7LtEcIi8VZDCd86agawhtuf4kdB2hvtvvU61tnU/ibiLuSX5gBGZXkgbjoOs66/OJ73iG7xelwCOa2SKjp0NSYr5DPLbZdPsDy6bQfaxpFtg@pJ4PPUDcNtnzDMu5a5g9orDikW0829wg9CehNTRs8I8qNZuIaNsG0KjkQiKk32tZ0HURWGu6oQM@AYw5ILo7CHSG64JYfSXf9eeTtuaCfbBPs0jG12tK9YWhvdzVntdr6j0noB3q6bUClNbX9E6GrExQB25E0vbcPit7hj1LF2PfQrlmWf2B6wXkwAiMPFBxdKdrJj6DpvGG5PPSZdpPFb1Fh7oT2jZZqywXJEm6v/vwzge7dw4b9x4eHD4rF6S9v358eFqWl5SRCR3HukyVJYhsNjgIhm9odKiiXkgLrKvlRbI0KSVPlgo5ssQkwSiEQSlHtI9Cx7GcDmEBubwmLTRhWIMeFowVNwwGYSAtQMyAdwk4mZQIB0LY8YJmm0IYC8iLQi53KX/o0WEFx6oZQGcJXfNwmmNLCzDabhCzP0gkkghPlpevxQHvNo4tR1rgGp56LjSFE@bJXXreCvuDImDPz1skakvbkhamnAzOVaZcli2oauwkjdR@vKTgdMOFqLUf47BmPqtEs8YljqFuEAz8oq53rKAbNvMwpPTH3vhecOzA@Kd64I2twI3KlOp9w4dZTR95xgDmNV@KepPIBzKRW30IMS902Jwlp5CnOL6BwAthTmXjiI14fs97zRmGSqkC5NH0wDjalt9lN5y@pun3gZpRmVpgmnrTcnR4zjdmH@Z30zXsmEXU48I8BU@sPtAPrX48L0M5H0A/Tw0JDAD0vECnZRw338cVYkg1NLeD9p0Tt3kmgCaXq7lpGFMBIvP6FDAtOF44NqM2NWMI80W72bRmmpQsN1NcjAXK3J4PSWBYNg6x7PpWmv8IAuLg@JTsHz8gbZiIUx3Gl4Q08R3XntOnHddm3ep7ZlSe5/wPnHQDB2NWIZrmB63y1iYUQkFwfRtvz3jmttYP2paON5AQAa@XsPEWCTF4Y0YGnz9DsxeLiABJaYbpsfeWRgfeNY1mMjWcryf0sVUrWRZ5sO1OMMJcKvPHjNC7ht@jts0GMYhilRmil4z/5Rx22nfPrOnuZ0B@n9ftQmV2DyAnBm6nHH9Sv/YsjZsd6dksDrRsFgeaCY9ogJmDQTKwRCXNeNh3A8tx@5bpOiABJnBcMB8eHxw2TnYf3y3XZD30Pd22mroDIhuwAQlt6tdklIiQuH2xmIlK/mzW2B7zXW@O71q8W1rzuiWJkneO8DdEzq5tmZPztIEQHRYM6g08Cvd5s/WPQqP1fez4ScI3I3NrK5KztaXDkk@DMd7n6Ebjvo/umG9Gpj/uN11oOEkP3L7ruGLtarbxk6fnnHXeEsCo2dYdqCaWQqh/d2v9iGvWVlifqR9J4jU9gCSABrpHbWr4VEBnV2U6CL6XLYPrHHeEuzzXakXC2qIeF2Y42CZ/IuI6COH3ebFm2IPu3JlUIEjecnA7BZvNialg9@GT3VPgSkanaThDw2cDeN54dIw@uA/SwAgUqYwQesvywYDQslsJLOaamQCHFk6eZ8bQgLXUhtZBDtQV8wTgCLvNbDuABXcTImOCxZg/GdtQa8OcYuhPMBOBWY0958RiasJkJPPWC9umaZdCNXrOrohJOiVHa1sq1UktMdrubMwNXD6l4kb14fHxyanMEz6OIf0QEvAmZYk47Kb7hhMatj0mI9igztutPjA8GMl@i96htKf7KCNHIP0eYJJw6riw1@0ceW5nIhZCzxtHNow9L9yPbGCYd7NhNBpBpEGm3zcCq5cPHUvrWdTOt6j@0cDomT5Mmi16nu8GfTuxaO/BcdqSOKGfXhn7ESIpNVbzhVvRMokHAjN90h0PsBMx0YN88OJSr2p1zP74HCUOGiJCDIw37kUS0olYcWGblh5/oo6FtuhtiWUYbZKpOSVYNCosB6xk4mwfszU8IjExKXEH1FEySJFR8x41WopaZPyKiacartdSTLVSXl/D0xZeKxXWbmPNhKU2ABmZUmV5KUNtn5J2ZnnxglNdbmdy1GmVMxlIjCKLSjqzpaSjXTWn5pywZKiIxQw7oBHZkWCQa04VEiJiQSrF0qAb9erje8d1pH9IzwNiOP6Iejxk0Bp6blLwPyZoLH2tFNbXf8iLK4V1vbBa5JXszVVV5bltHoUtLkb5H9ZkCTNANPVD0ZsvdAKXnkn5lhlSjAMSD2dgpOuLi4mn@YHN69dDnHr1Fe1C08hi99GNZ9oOOXnR/eijZzs7qwdk9UDuDjnweZdkn92CyLzxgFDbOiIPjvfJ6fEBpd7R0mUWLi1bXdF16Pz2y5fxP3/AXxs/L/HCUurB/l7OVJAhgcJ19eUnV1998i73mkT0LFmEB2xYKU68kLIrGEJ4dkWgi11TX1rSYelUWRK/XSyVMofHRxmyWKnUpEIWmkFmruOapK@QH3Q65p2@9eQHz59vu64r2@4defuH5dX3Tm8UCgAosRRVWmzRNu5KTjED5Zeu70qLVhsQpNEwB3bo40fXbYm0FXU7rUrXLSDlB28lEzb2llvRdTMlNZsFubpOJQjzIG0uqIbgttoxqJZPtB7vvb/faKSN02B1CUz6fvM4YpRgXrMcRb3gAaWcqvqKLkDigAgMyjOjtiG7z488K6D6yoq@famvXJakCiHD0VO42O3pCCuj7154OkquWFj0iJ/p0mRlAn4N5B1BT0fzgE9j265BPb0exS9pa2uL8E9SxNKwVFmFq1DAf2lICIRUkvTlouv2eF0blsgOunzxxZ3hTMju5OQ9uQG5APDsSAAYlqoNuZ5K8CuxsNzqhzslpKksltLJbYW8GC7dAWPQDkYo397SaMcJ23RPJo3ZgTJkMcBIdxY5KMXjPZYbw0WCIlcLpYpE3niVKgX0xJ2lISdc3MlNXDuLKcktI/yR3GAMCce1V7ohgWMlrMB7Yzih5y2SJq@U1AE9BfdP7OwnG7Cz@FbZ0PVDGTpvmdzbJHfJPUJaHLG0tCQZy5ud5fXOzc7Go60TdoHv5Y5j2G7PsR7Ix9GVlzAYjuScHMLHgY8JnwA@Lnws@LTkUoV4sKi03JFDgpHLKjZt4wpHyRh2ie6IhAPS8Sh1ONVcILIBJOgCiFU8q9MNmERBn@Zl5aYdUq5qSg4rpNS/A/UbLH8nITFfIpG15Dvbjj4AW@a6a76AP8tzbL5gAcyjuDBRwnu6lqZ4F/pZulk5KVzhGvmFN0lcfYvGd9AbYQrJPX6kSzOfmED4kBMXeK2Q8AqyBJfmSZF852ekKFI5p32FGZ7vqU80VVqFLBC3@8vwwWuZXFzWr37@T3/83S9f/Y9tuKZndPdf/dfV51@/iv@u/u5vrj759z/8Bm6//wJuCezqk88A8rN/vfr8d1ef/ILdP7v62b9hmeG//SkWxT9jTmrffpyqCdirr37/xauv4uoffjuHkdF9M8n17SdI/Q2IZGonxQiSj8GYz7@OCL796atvBAnU/vCbpPztx1AGQvY/UWQCgPi3TGEE57BvsPGf/@7VV6/@909f/MOv04eGUP/66tP/vPr0V1ef/gdumTXcOle1Ej6ylXopKmZLqXulUqlXsheX1RJcHJ3NVzT417R8qaThlc9GCF6taBEeSCtaRauXssCfzUcChJQKh@RLSC@YORtDIwVERaWuKGr0p5YqinheKGCVotYRhGU1ql9CuVS5ZJQXCFFKF5dKcnFBQBT985oSqxGIqqJU69V6RFNXocqR7AlYRKN8vDPRCAAOoGFUSKty6goz6wIElZTJ6y9kTpUZoSICiOIar7M/xjOpM624yomZocoF0S4bZVnNbm9nxV90295OAbMJIPlPEWfl7XNN@@FYIuXx9rgs86ONbeWGWvbpT7Zxc1@2aUCaN0CbDLn3IAxOA29JkeUbsu94NAiME9hU7GXBluwYRMm2TXu@cVeWNO1h5rmlPD6zNss7@l7/gzW1CqFWqVVrcKvpcNNrVR1upQr@8TIDs0f0V6vVdQZCNBZrtbxe9zGjvPrbfzzdffJwd/@P//fZn774xa@sM7dPsXD1z1/t5HqGvBltuJwPfLwMvGh8DVJl0/Kj2pklrjM6c529NEwrfSGNYbLPKAzDkWA/myaBq8cfkMrEXZB0W6qrrr78@OrLz6@@/PurL39@9S/w/0v8//K/5df4LT15aVtNwhOuFUkkXpjPbtyU2mXb6DdbBnGK7JTEyWW8ZnxKIrXKzQx@VVM7b7fxk8m2lUyeHd1A3p9Rs81MguLlTP7MhQyvrRypeABzBFlllZ@95DL8rAAK/Ms7KKTfyoCqOIPM1FXJLOPLFx71fbd5pmzlDg6P7u8@PjzIaQ92nzWe7t17fIqwxoPDB437h08O7@dWVX5yofC25ZsbN6mDmhUzH8lSWmrWzLchW@4qaq6Z2dGhsS3KqKDVfuBZAyVTzqjq60VycHyq2VaPkvPNDdK3HKtv2IT2Q9sI8O2bqVd3rDZ7qSV@z2fkej2fdKlHc3i2M7Jsm8HwRArca6P4HPSDh@eHpBl2fC4EaFsu9Z0MFyEk4Ks3A89tGk17TBw8/wlcQs8DSLSBI3k9h6G61B7wo0ROgQqCruUTowktNNhbEjli@D3Sp9HLOCb2hBP4@GIL7lnh0R@LsycAOlyA2TVgvEICIkWB5I99iUUZP393bV@EGhkYXmAZtiQxS1KHcDzGQD9pF6UFaFXHM/qkTNpR2PVp3/XGAKk@BFPqKxu3bq1vCGh17dZGET5ZMEMRvGodaEVZalE7Lkse7Vj4OoEPBBeZeyeZIlk9hz1LjmRO76Uq@89YZXX16CgnLWQOsIq6ke4kKR/ci8pAtBvxMAl7KZa9iOVSattGhyvfPwLgkWH7SHGcrjxPV07TlZO4cilJePBCPc/1lL7fUZnnMNrb8uGjR8ePiuQCwJfwiNt8w7uUVWkBeihPz61AKahcSIcGDeyIBp4NKigJC2Ck8HAsoIoeq9fZ2yiMBCIAm1UUdmQgHTXDAMMLz@XxJKglhGRA8ZQcki2TAkKD0HOYvClzRniqiubYLhgzZaW00LXmQYU4BbClEtlUSZbYriQ9OrxzigGEvcT7F7uP3ffYHbqV9xQPBd65deS7u3v/CHkvoj5WuBDWD2qOLJLd@4Da56j9SdT@/Sh8FK4uQR0gao@j9iZRe4higSZ0PfZCoeouMp0kqmLMPmJYEAtNMeYAMQf3EkUxZu@uJAIJJkPXHrKvlb3@JvO6188BuAMtn0AWNtDNODH5luMHhmNSBUlhJkEuYAOOyG1Vr19nHT8Bo5163FFCyxwrUBEIZOV5Pb23e3qIXVqNehD6K0ei2kFUO5nAnaRxETRFG0nAKIdpsBHFLLf/tMqt0XWySd4jm3VmHhsqERwWUe4CDgEi5ixOVibrzEW86UwgOChH0pqkBfxaAclw3QJBq1DEpRO9CJMzNhu5kAIlJ6MK/TozJEPHp0FMhAIsWAA8agZiZBLDNGElxAEqVGbLU0IjW5bBmHM8MZekhXSjVmNb@ljdYNWolVPDebqxC3FzYw7UxYMCkSk9BUYWjXBu63RcqJBrciNnNMWKDN@nsCBFYtfeJJVbfa3UaMbaVADUcL0GOBWjdmp8xDhgDwc25SOFdnKka3W6bIhFFIBoGYHBIx7GAGBU7m4kTXuAkUHIsUUr3b40/r0IHWGF8GRuF3rrXAlDR0HEuofFUVvGtZjP7BhQUewEIP4iEVJcXTtni0zaBu4kf9JJOYb6s13l2q03ecqPEDmisJZFawLyCdeoadelGBg9p@Sdz0gjyln/gR3gG6sDi94mU5Ysr1zkO4VHNI2KbpoYiN@rp@Khn@qm2S6K28XW2rnBwdbbGQx4qCAMAlZhDn75DOR/uTCaXs5FQE349V0iKl6k5rk11YEgmPfgpF@m0cno4t6ZwadG59yAgbbMwTCfArZriZaKoIrEizZGVVIBJbfbxQSglSO1wn8RJi0PjHyzwPY8kdcKTWI/kSkIhYjIWRPkYMVb6CMO7FCvcWaaDb8L@YRiurCQYerCOe15ewS2Ptqxg7Cc@MbCtweEjCKZszsF8rRqC1K9wkZj3R2wjYnvmQWIOT@Yv0NCNGDiVvJpAKEqx65NYSfWG2yRH9oomwlawcdaeg8NiqcilnMAK0syqphh1NM6JnlVcoPZDSwxx3POkeJPt//c9fjOENhzaM90wzdZu3GeZxQdUVLJC14GFlVMigPIuKNRUpxIDU5PmA3cXVhTiYZLdDzc04S56REXiXcHYvs4sZamhIKls@kNikTlOGtdh48GJ6eZNXyWfE2aXQ1FREG@xsYevuzohYPgmhhO4TF619iGK87j@LI0h4ztlzAP52I3lXQ2oYpsAuVzGuRZ3WKztfgBQ5lkMmzD1Gp5SZ9AdsE2i6Mu/hYGhfHtm0NHQGR2PYUpQyaVEXJ@nu7xjSIjBelLkJQ0YUnoMYTQCoSARwjPaDk4erMmvVqLRSXzgWP1YauABxbs50TBWoHEP/@AlQXLbE3JpGb0a5mFD4EvrsTMEuu4UPzqiiWF4OhWkfBzs6JYlbifO3EZY3h6iOeQdX21mBpdHHTr7dJezJO2CCbfXAVNq@e3jvCHWdCcJrXdEUrd2EykisE316CNreLMdMcQtzcSAdNTcXrCgaU/NZtwoWarmEQ8ppxRxeSpoTh0hEqRpHZgybYOB50quFr0nbm0hAvbPMuWeEKwxOTu4I1KxASjSpiZsdfuclGCRp2wTz0DBi8meDi82Y/zWFKTih4kfWkNFM9wOlTBnstBx23AfROSpGraQ4JPtDyqiRbFVWZxnW1v0kFaFRkNM5IdjPFzOCVFxGyHqXNiRDP8vAkp8MaopGs4LZtlxhPqWAV2hPhaGoyiv6LjQxxoqREnh07Pwa@YU3xFPtygHu/9hHwFj16PPatjOYZN4qFqMB82x2QnOXWFbaJ4Mw3txV935GEPaPbAlC56mb2@aeiFjdu3b97Sb24WtjbFetG2zhvs7FlBTsg82NvMOWI7ZZznwakSwSNV20k2tfi9JtRhFtO0DDhYwRNIzsiWLHUlQzLIhyKr2hrb7zkEpl3IP8M@P4Sl7HAWy@yVSYsdrfoU9yUQerC3wDcAUUg8I8syVlnY5czJeBPKuWl@mb@UqK2vsTpy2EiPiori3RBsElhtq7BFsoq@xnjsqlWP2ZI5GSd2/72tW9n1NRVNEGua@NHYzKludKDL2586zs37AxtWrUzNyTDv28JBsKpO@4Z1Sdoz7GeiiVsk3mL0yq5vFTezxeJatnjz9orWz23LUuiMDDapA361YJjUOnMHvqJeXFbrpUour2VlVAlCYYTgT7F8Pv23qUfJSCcuYDyuXoness6RXfHW9zL/8aJ2ZBs9VeraAwyFZehxZmD5mpiCJvvQt0nYZMQ3JH1joIjJxsSTOpLJgky1yvo4akk9x5qvqtW1Yv3NimCH5rRU8Waswn8Px/tehmQYWavFNdyeABlKY/QCxLAAU9XXG@u5jdvmxrpUit8bgqCh7EeFUQjAlIg/g4X@wgwL0juVsFdjW26KCy@TlDTSvUMD/EEc6U5jcaIyidueguOVuZEhWmWewq46h7yBxJ0BUcyir0qapuF7Y9/V/MRQUqmUUVyeKCjv/wE)

Next answer must not exceed 5185 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6946 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M eliF MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 2d2b 5b2a  ODeerF$}++++-+[*
00000050: 2f2f 2f6f 7066 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a7a 667a  ///opfzzfzzfzzfz
00000060: 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a66 6666 7a66 667a  zzfzzfzfzfffzffz
00000070: 7a7a 7a7a 6666 7a66 7a7a 7a66 667a 667a  zzzzffzfzzzffzfz
00000080: 7a7a 667a 667a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a7a 7a66  zzfzfzfzzfzfzzzf
00000090: 7a66 7a66 7a7a 667a 667a 6666 667a 7a66  zfzfzzfzfzfffzzf
000000a0: 7a66 7a7a 7a66 7a66 6666 66e2 a086 e2a1  zfzzzfzffff.....
000000b0: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086  ................
000000c0: e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  ................
000000d0: a086 e2a1 865c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062  .....\. /+ #\. b
000000e0: 6173 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c  asename "$(readl
000000f0: 696e 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865  ink /proc/$$/exe
00000100: 2922 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720  )"|rev;:<<'EOF' 
00000110: 233e 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  #>>\.1+///      
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f              O\./
00000130: 2a20 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f  * .ggcGmiV.ZZ;oo
00000140: 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f  o"loG";?=0%S!11o
00000150: 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65  oo<"><>".#define
00000160: 2053 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a   S"C"       //A.
00000170: 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c  #ifdef __cpluspl
00000180: 7573 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020  us//l. f();     
00000190: 2020 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c         //i.#incl
000001a0: 7564 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23  ude<cstdio>//c.#
000001b0: 6465 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f  define S"++C" //
000001c0: 650a 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020  e. int///       
000001d0: 2020 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020    ".#endif//    
000001e0: 2020 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f     \..#ifdef __O
000001f0: 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322  BJC__.#define S"
00000200: 432d 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e  C-evitceJbO".#en
00000210: 6469 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e  dif. main(){prin
00000220: 7466 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69  tf(S)/*/main(){i
00000230: 6d70 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b  mport std.stdio;
00000240: 2244 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f  "D".write/**/;}/
00000250: 2a7d 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757  *}<.>  vwWWWWwWW
00000260: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000270: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000280: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757  wWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW
00000290: 7776 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777  wvwWWwWWWwvWwwww
000002a0: 7777 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757  wwwwwwwWWWwWWWWW
000002b0: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
000002c0: 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWwWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000300: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000320: 5757 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwwWWWWWWW
00000330: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWWWwww
00000340: 7777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wwwWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000350: 5757 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757  WWWWWWWWwwwwwWWW
00000360: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000370: 5757 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39  WWWwwwwwwwwwww.9
00000380: 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939  99 999 99.999 99
00000390: 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131  9 9.999v<>000011
000003a0: 3031 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67  0110.v  <>"efung
000003b0: 652d 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779  e-98",,,,,,,,,7y
000003c0: 332d 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020  3-v< @.>  #^Gv  
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040                 @
000003e0: 2c22 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020  ,"B"_"Tr",,@.   
000003f0: 763c 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933  v<[_"]Befunge-93
00000400: 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c  ">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
00000410: 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d  .   >#<"Befunge-
00000420: 3936 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020  96"> ^v$G001.v  
00000430: 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB
00000440: 2220 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  " _             
00000450: 2020 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c       v<.>  ,,,,,
00000460: 4023 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e  @#      ,"79-egn
00000470: 7566 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031  uferT"_v# $G0001
00000480: 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  <>.             
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004a0: 203c 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020   <>10000G$v.    
000004b0: 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c   #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,
000004c0: 2c40 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461  ,@#"79-egnuferda
000004d0: 7551 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020  uQ"_100000G$v.  
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237              ,,"7
00000500: 392d 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31  9-egnufetniuQ"_1
00000510: 3030 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c  000000G$!v@,,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,.        
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2020 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470      "79-egnufetp
00000560: 6553 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39  eS"_"Sexefunge-9
00000570: 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  7"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,
00000580: 4023 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  @#,.            
00000590: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005a0: 2020 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2026 2049 3820     <>"v"@. & I8 
000005b0: 4820 4920 2064 2020 2020 2020 2424 240a  H I  d      $$$.
000005c0: 6126 3867 2633 6734 6736 5239 5050 5050  a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPP
000005d0: 5050 3c0a 3e22 676e 616c 6f6b 6e69 4d22  PP<.>"gnalokniM"
000005e0: 4f4f 4f4f 4f4f 4f4f 4f2e 0a20 402c 2246  OOOOOOOOO.. @,"F
000005f0: 222c 2275 222c 226e 222c 2263 222c 2274  ","u","n","c","t
00000600: 222c 226f 222c 2269 222c 2264 223c 3e20  ","o","i","d"<> 
00000610: 7265 6420 646f 776e 2074 776f 2072 6564  red down two red
00000620: 206c 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77   left one yellow
00000630: 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079   up green down y
00000640: 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064  ellow up green d
00000650: 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074 6872 6565  own red up three
00000660: 2072 6564 2072 6967 6874 2074 776f 2079   red right two y
00000670: 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  ellow down yello
00000680: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
00000690: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
000006a0: 646f 776e 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  down one yellow 
000006b0: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067  down blue left g
000006c0: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 646f  reen down red do
000006d0: 776e 2074 776f 2072 6564 206c 6566 7420  wn two red left 
000006e0: 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 7965  one yellow up ye
000006f0: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c  llow down blue l
00000700: 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072  eft green down r
00000710: 6564 206c 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7265 6420  ed left one red 
00000720: 646f 776e 2074 6872 6565 2079 656c 6c6f  down three yello
00000730: 7720 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f  w down yellow do
00000740: 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265  wn blue left gre
00000750: 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074  en down red up t
00000760: 776f 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965  wo green down ye
00000770: 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  llow up yellow d
00000780: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 7265  own blue left re
00000790: 6420 7570 2074 6872 6565 2072 6564 2072  d up three red r
000007a0: 6967 6874 2074 776f 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  ight two yellow 
000007b0: 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  down yellow down
000007c0: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2030 3030 3131   blue left 00011
000007d0: 3130 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  1000010000010001
000007e0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030  0000010000010100
000007f0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000000000100
00000800: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100010000010001
00000810: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030  0000010000010100
00000820: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
00000830: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000100010000
00000840: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031  0000010001000001
00000850: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3030  0001000110000100
00000860: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100010000010001
00000870: 3130 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  1000010000010001
00000880: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031  0000010001000001
00000890: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0000010000010001
000008a0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031  0000010001000001
000008b0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000000000100
000008c0: 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100000100010001
000008d0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3130  0000000110000110
000008e0: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131  0000110000010011
000008f0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0000010001000100
00000900: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3130 3031  0100010000001001
00000910: 3130 3131 3130 3030 3030 3031 3130 3031  1011100000011001
00000920: 3131 3130 3030 3131 3030 3131 3030 3030  1110001100110000
00000930: 3030 3031 3030 3131 3130 3031 3131 3130  0001001110011110
00000940: 3030 3031 3130 3131 3130 3030 3030 3130  0001101110000010
00000950: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
00000960: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
00000970: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
00000980: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030 3031  0000001000110001
00000990: 3130 3131 3131 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  1011110001000100
000009a0: 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3031 3030  0100000100010100
000009b0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010000000100010
000009c0: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
000009d0: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
000009e0: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
000009f0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 300a 3031  0000000100110.01
00000a00: 2026 2026 2620 2626 2620 2020 2020 2620   & && &&&     & 
00000a10: 7b7d 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372  {}]........laocr
00000a20: 6168 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  ahC.............
00000a30: c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2  ................
00000a40: 86a8 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3  ................
00000a50: 9fe2 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690  ................
00000a60: e289 a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286  ................
00000a70: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2  ................
00000a80: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a90: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f  ................
00000aa0: c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692  ................
00000ab0: e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000ac0: 92e2 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000ad0: 86a8 c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82  ................
00000ae0: e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000af0: 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c  ................
00000b00: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2  ................
00000b10: 86a8 c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
00000b20: cf80 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2  ................
00000b30: 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2  ................
00000b40: a1ce b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000b50: e296 b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2  ................
00000b60: bbf0 9f98 ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f  .....Emotinomico
00000b70: 6ef0 9f98 b2e2 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 2b2d  n.............+-
00000b80: 2b5b 2d2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e  +[-++++[-<+++++>
00000b90: 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b  ]<[-<++++++<++++
00000ba0: 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3e 2b7b 7d5b  +<+++++>>>]>+{}[
00000bb0: 3c3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e  <<<<+++++++.>-.>
00000bc0: 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b  ---.<<-----.++++
00000bd0: 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e  ++++.-----.>--.>
00000be0: 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e2d 3e2d 5d3c 2b5b  ---.<+.>>->-]<+[
00000bf0: 3c3c 2b2e 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<+.<+++++++++++
00000c00: 2b2e 3e3e 2b2e 3c2b 2b2b 2e3c 2d2d 2e3e  +.>>+.<+++.<--.>
00000c10: 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2b 2b2b  +.--------.<++++
00000c20: 2e3e 2b2e 3e3e 7b7d 5d3e 5d28 2829 2829  .>+.>>{}]>](()()
00000c30: 2829 2829 2829 293c 3e28 2829 2829 293c  ()()())<>(()())<
00000c40: 3e7b 287b 7d5b 2829 5d29 3c3e 287b 287b  >{({}[()])<>({({
00000c50: 7d29 287b 7d5b 2829 5d29 7d7b 7d29 3c3e  })({}[()])}{})<>
00000c60: 7d3c 3e28 2829 7b5b 2829 5d28 3c7b 7d28  }<>((){[()](<{}(
00000c70: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929  (((((((((()()())
00000c80: 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d  {}){}){}){}()){}
00000c90: 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b  )((()()()()){}){
00000ca0: 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28  })[(([][]){}){}(
00000cb0: 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829  )])([]()){})[]()
00000cc0: 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829  )(([[][]()]([]()
00000cd0: 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b  ((((([][][])){}{
00000ce0: 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 293e  })[]){})))[]())>
00000cf0: 297d 7b7d 297b 7b7d 283c 2828 2828 2828  )}{}){{}(<((((((
00000d00: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b  ((((((((()()()){
00000d10: 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29  }){}){}){}()){})
00000d20: 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d  ((()()()()){}){}
00000d30: 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829  )[(([][]){}){}()
00000d40: 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929  ])([]()){})[]())
00000d50: 5b5b 5d28 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d29 5b5b  [[]()()()])[])[[
00000d60: 5d28 2928 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d5b 5d5b  ]()()()()])[][][
00000d70: 5d5b 2829 5d29 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829  ][()])((((((()()
00000d80: 2829 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  ()){}()){}){}){}
00000d90: 295b 2829 2829 5d29 3e29 7d7b 7d28 7b20  )[()()])>)}{}({ 
00000da0: 2d7d 5f3d 2229 2b3b 3b2b 3b2b 3b2b 3b2b  -}_=")+;;+;+;+;+
00000db0: 3b3b 2b3b 2b3b 3b2b 3b3b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b  ;;+;+;;+;;;+;;+;
00000dc0: 2b3b 2b3b 2b3b 2b3b 2b3b 3b3b 2b3b 3b2b  +;+;+;+;+;;;+;;+
00000dd0: 3b3b 2b3b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b 3b3b 2b3b 3b2b  ;;+;;+;;+;;;+;;+
00000de0: 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b 2b22 3b78 2d2d 3f79 0a20  ;+;;+;+";x--?y. 
00000df0: 3d79 3b79 3d22 7972 7275 4322 3b28 2129  =y;y="yrruC";(!)
00000e00: 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e3d 6c65 7420 6221  =seq;main=let b!
00000e10: 5f3d 2222 696e 2070 7574 5374 7224 2822  _=""in putStr$("
00000e20: 2221 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b  "!"snrettaPgnaB+
00000e30: 2229 2b2b 792d 2d3f 226c 6c65 6b73 6148  ")++y--?"lleksaH
00000e40: 220a 2d2d 4e27 5a69 2854 6a69 383d 402f  ".--N'Zi(Tji8=@/
00000e50: 426d 5532 295b 2d5d 3c3e 5c5b 5c3c 3e5c  BmU2)[-]<>\[\<>\
00000e60: 5c2f 3c3e 5c2f 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 3c3e 3c3e  \/<>\/\[/\/\<><>
00000e70: 3c3e 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 2f3c 3e5c 2f2f 5c2f  <>\[/\/\/<>\//\/
00000e80: 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5c 5d2f 5c2f  <><><><><>\\]/\/
00000e90: 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f 5c5d 2f5c 2f5c 5c2e 2f5d  /\//\/\]/\/\\./]
00000ea0: 732a 2f2f 2fe2 8899 5341 564e 4143 efbd  s*///...SAVNAC..
00000eb0: 90f0 9f92 ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e  .....ijome......
00000ec0: a140 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e  .@,ka"89-egnufen
00000ed0: 5573 7373 7373 6161 6161 6165 6565 6565  Usssssaaaaaeeeee
00000ee0: 6565 6565 6570 6165 6565 6565 6565 6565  eeeeepaeeeeeeeee
00000ef0: 6563 6973 6165 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969  ecisaeeeeeeejiii
00000f00: 6969 6969 696a 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  iiiiijeeeeeeeeee
00000f10: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6a7a 6163 6969 6969  eeeeeeeejzaciiii
00000f20: 6969 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565 6561 6365  iiiiiiiiijeeeace
00000f30: 6561 6365 7775 7575 7765 656a 6969 6969  eacewuuuweejiiii
00000f40: 6a69 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565  jiiiiiiiiiiijeee
00000f50: 6161 6161 6b65 6561 6161 6177 7677 3b2b  aaaakeeaaaawvw;+
00000f60: 3b3b 2b3b 2b3b 3b3b 3b2b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b  ;;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;
00000f70: 3b2b 3b2b 3b3b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b e2a0 80e2  ;+;+;;;+;;+;....
00000f80: a096 e2a0 97e2 a08e e2a2 8ee2 a2a6 e2a2  ................
00000f90: a6e2 a0ae 22                             ...."
```

## Explanation:

Boolfuck uses bits instead of bytes/integers. `-` is now a noop, and `;` replaces `.`. Using `-+` to get boolfuck in the desired state works without affecting brainfuck. All that is needed is to make sure we don't go into an infinite loop or output a bit we shouldn't, and squeeze "+;;+;+;+;+;;+;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;+;+;+;+;;;+;;+;;+;;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;;+;+;;;+;;+;" into the program. The reason it's split into two portions is because the four `;`s would interfere with the proper output, so it was split at a point where there were four `;`s.

Comment: Congrats! It looks like you won!

Answer (score 12):

## 3. [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 106 bytes

```
void main(){import std.stdio;"D".write;}
/*                        ;ooo"><>"
1j U8=XPC#18M<<}9F ,+;q,+;
*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0OzOjO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrZVclPTKizJLUq1rufS1FHAA6/z8fCU7GzslLsMshVAL24gAZ2VDC18bm1pLNwUdbetCIObS0v//HwA)

This program prints **D** in D, **emmoS** in Somme, and **><>** in ><>.

Next answer cannot exceed **146 bytes** (106 + 40).

## Explanation

`;ooo"><>"` prints "><>" in ><> (which is a palindrome), then exits.

Comment: I like this one a lot :D

Comment: It took me a few seconds to get why the reverse of `><>` is not `<><`...

Comment: Any reason for all the extra whitespace?

Comment: Somme... I didn't want to interfere with it.

Answer (score 12):

## 4. C, 125 bytes

```
void main(){//\
/*;ooo"><>"
printf("C")/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
J'zvSfN0cb&)}kf ;K-+ ,+;q,+;60d}[}q(-6+:puupd"*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcMxDsIgFADQnVOQPyhQ29@pg5guOmni4qhLhWKIttBKa6Lh7NiXPJWrV9M/Upqd1bRrbM/4D/FGUEjnHNS7GogfbR8Mgz1wFGg778ZA30EXS@skHKD4jDa0KATKiIIc19/5Ys6luq94fBoqT3lGN5kcllWp4zUOLK@yrZ8mr0FgSn8) (I picked clang, but works with gcc as well.)

This program prints **C** in C, **D** in D, **emmoS** in Somme, and **><>** in ><>.

Next answer cannot exceed 165 bytes (125 + 40).

### Explanation

This takes advantage of the fact that single-line comments in C can be extended to the next line by escaping the newline with a backslash, while in D that is (apparently) not possible. This means that the `/*` on line 2 starts a multi-line comment in D, while in C it does not. Also makes use of the fact that `/*/` can act as both start and end of a multi-line comment in both languages.
The ><> part works exactly the same as in previous answers, and the Somme part was generated anew with [this script](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Somme/blob/master/somme-help.rb).

Answer (score 9):

## 1. D, 40 bytes

```
void main(){import std.stdio;"D".write;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S/n/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0OzOjO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrZVclPTKizJLUq1r//8HAA)

One byte language names!

Comment: One byte language name is easy to reverse, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

## 2. [Somme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Somme), 73 bytes

```
void main(){import std.stdio;"D".write;}
/*
1j U8=XPC#18M<<}9F ,+;q,+;
*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87PzU39/78sPzNFITcxM09DszoztyC/qEShuCRFD4gz862VXJT0yosyS1Kta7n0tbgMsxRCLWwjApyVDS18bWxqLd0UdLStC4GYS0v//38A)

This program prints **D** in D, and **emmoS** in Somme.

Next answer cannot exceed **113 bytes** (73 + 40).

### Explanation

Somme adds up each column and treats the result as commands. For example, the first column is `v/1*`, which sums to [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P78opVjBViE4xMXTT68oNTFFLzkjsahYLzexQKFaoSa1RiFVD6hGQVfB2Eihlqsotbg0pwSoAaRPr7g0V0FVwdJUQRsoy1WgAJUFGlH0/3@ZvqEWAA).

This translates (roughly) into:

```
Asi:8+::2+:47*-m,;
A                   push 10
                    [10]
 s                  square it
                    [100]
  i                 increment
                    [101]
   :                duplicate
                    [101, 101]
    8+              add 8
                    [101, 109]
      ::            duplicate twice
                    [101, 109, 109, 109]
        2+          add 2
                    [101, 109, 109, 111]
          :         duplicate
                    [101, 109, 109, 111, 111]
           47*-     subtract 28
                    [101, 109, 109, 111, 83]
               m,   output each as a character
                    emmoS
                 ;  terminate
```

You can plug in the other rows and the target column [with this script](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Somme/blob/master/somme-help.rb).

Answer (score 7):

## 9. [Befunge-93](https://github.com/TryItOnline/befunge-97-mtfi), 221 bytes

```
void main(){//\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
>"Befunge-98";"Befunge-93",,,,,,,,,,@;9k,@
 ,wVkk_,xeWvl<h_VZUn*///⎚laocrahC
```

Thanks to @JoKing for pointing out that I forgot a `9`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NasJAFIX38wpuhutGh8S7cFMZCWJcuXERmkIoDNHcqdeYGUmnsSC@Qh@gj9cXSbPpz4ED5@OcxdmTfXMvFC/mcRMs933nuZJNyW4yvSE@C1SjrOF8VBTaew/JMgExrsiyI5nBkNkOJI3ZrbepMf@6mDoOBzrtd8OKXMVWXFp2wU4ghWyKCrm5@DbI11DNBrPXsIHZteVAqBTqOyqRwPrn4QPoP5hD9KuVXtTRSsjomte1id7pqTsvjyYvHp1CxK@Pz3PpD215TPv@Gw)

[Try it online! (Vim)](https://tio.run/##TYxBasMwEEX3ukI2QoWQCNtD002DgwhxV91kYZqCKQjHkmvVtmRs2TGUXqEH6PF6EUfdxB34MO//mX9Ou2KastRihgdVB5kREo2juAFmyw1ygP1u9kxvm94GdnRvIOQAuq8qvGHLe/RXNcfTNBglcJ0qvVp/ArwhoIu4VqdFkoTGGMJ2jKA7IXOlJY6J21XuCHN@PDxHnP/LfDkom8mP89FdSS1UjppWaZuvSETiNVBQdWNaizsrAidlQvJEgkurrARKIfwCihg5yLzX79LfPpJwhgfi3WYfbktvj7B3OZUl90b5OlS7gp@SF00B4Pf7p0pN1qZFdAU)

Prints `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93, along with maintaining the other outputs in the other languages.

Next answer cannot exceed **287** bytes.

Will work in MTFI,  and input must be given for PyFunge.

## Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 206d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a  void main(){//\.
00000010: 2f2a 1b53 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 223e  /*.SmiV.ZZ;ooo">
00000020: 3c3e 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 220a  <>".#define S"".
00000030: 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a  #ifdef __OBJC__.
00000040: 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 2d65 7669 7463  #define S"-evitc
00000050: 656a 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966 0a70 7269  ejbO".#endif.pri
00000060: 6e74 6628 2243 2253 292f 2a2f 696d 706f  ntf("C"S)/*/impo
00000070: 7274 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422  rt std.stdio;"D"
00000080: 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 0a3e  .write/**/;}/*.>
00000090: 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3822 3b22 4265  "Befunge-98";"Be
000000a0: 6675 6e67 652d 3933 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-93",,,,,,,
000000b0: 2c2c 2c40 3b39 6b2c 400a 202c 7756 6b6b  ,,,@;9k,@. ,wVkk
000000c0: 5f2c 7865 5776 6c3c 685f 565a 556e 2a2f  _,xeWvl<h_VZUn*/
000000d0: 2f2f e28e 9a6c 616f 6372 6168 43         //...laocrahC
```

## How?

Befunge-93 does not know what `;` is (in Befunge-98, it skips commands until the next `;`), so it ignores it. Allowing us to distinguish the two versions of Befunge. Also, the Somme portion was modified to work using [this script](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Somme/blob/master/somme-help.rb)

Comment: You've forgotten the `9` before the `k,` for Befunge-98.

Comment: There, think it's fixed NOW @JoKing

Answer (score 7):

## 10. FreeDOS COM file, 277 bytes

This should work in MS-DOS and DOSbox too, but I can't test that right now, so better safe than sorry.

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh )X5  M!M elif MOC SODeerF$*/main(){//\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
>"Befunge-98";"Befunge-93";,,,,,,,,,,@
 ,wVkJ7-;l(e[Kt!m[*///⎚laocrahC
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRnZVttI9hn9wrzcGBpJYFs2JIQYzARs06GbBE5MMnSM45alkq2gxUcL2J1Of8J8wHze/Ejm3qqSLC9J95kZzsFU1d3XumWGZjz@@nUTTm0bTGAjMx0F5iUkIe4moTcbeWECCYsTGJtRwOIYhjN447L2b@zTfThUNqEVep45iRmUWqHNSmAGNpROo1HqsyCJSxAzK3HDIAYnjGDIkoRFwKYTFrkssJiiWGYCJ2AhrZKEqTWGSeQioYKsXQdmYQom6ZYxLINv3jOI04iRln5ou84MUEJ1MoM4hGSM/JIxmyEJAzewvNRmNi7oEDw3uFeYNQ6hEkBpq15C0YK2cLpHp3YY06lyefrmx3enP3YGF2/andtmXTn75abTbZa2tEcLKtYxKa6XFCcNuJngmcEoNUdM0z8rG5xnaRO2FrlUYatehi3OCf2J7i0pG1fvbq7f3RDjIcYEWXNNkPVG5/a607rptAkmOKLiv0fsgYDoox4eCOoSPGniJiMoQf@IzA6UDalKBx1vJeiPHKcMI4xwRk@IUzeBurLhuMrGkvEoX1syZbeukxaCewXufpWc7n4ll3MHn2QR/UIxHSfJJG4YxshNxumwaoW@cRPNLpKrAGPDjCSauUmYrRkzfDPGjDEeI3OCORMjh8zDUKK8LEGJC@drZQ5D40u2b0MlSgOeXUVgN/R9TNVSlGI2G@EkMWI6EZ/VaLhCcHJ8guiTWTIOg31B4bjxmH9Q4i3jtxCbY1mVxLKMoRsY@He9Mi2sLCs0vZxE7vPFOgHvXR/xH1wfKjEHAq6riT@BE8NmD0aQeh7snWzXYXsbqMQkuMjjaviJavOBVUjdEek3hTA/tATfSlg84yKQZdVYOiwyPmNYDiNWeXGY2TTMT7gvnOHQXTEpp9pfoXpe8RPHNegDKpX8eF/y4AmAtXQD55gy7asutK5eg@N6DC6vWqeXl78UxCyjFOIqar6kKDxhHVDvguNJxE54kZ@oSoZHtUndzKIcDycs0FTCUPVqxExb0xucXrOogYWRrVn6SXN/jxqj2B3X957TzoIAa88N1OOTbZV52EMddXvzs0D6cqSWWWA3VRULLFPo2OCqHBuk1l1wF1zz0mrQUuWtVNaaJCjdBT0sL8CSFkX1pN@7ubjqE/4bNk2wW8eP2JD9FDs8KcOmFqP2gIXO29NJfX//72K5U9836rWG2Ow@rem66F1VYra5Ca/Y1E79Ce1KynRq8@D8HiM3NTY@GoA/hlpwLVekkTcEasNYHsbm5tzRojV//foQujYYO@PLJ7eVl3D9cfzHH7cvX9baUGuXxhNx@GEM@u0zgNdPXgPz0POvr1rQvWozFp1v7WAfcQPsyYZxpxg7f@v67vu/ffhwFIYhr21l02YOuge6JVy7Du5gMLg6@6k1GBRgFfbgJhb7NLxCLAyO60h7NKz4rm7sGK4/CaME4sSu4q8bHmEjqj5GbsKMnR3j6Iuxo5wU6@OomPZH5fznpQLlx/f3Pz2vHHka6/2cPPF7O4Zh/Puf//LM0IrMceurE4U@/Oa5QxBSdxQpHS8QdvBUcZqe6Q9tE4IGT9KgrEbDPEkVuzlU6aq5mzoO/aq7jqZWKWhV9Luq7w7VBZBIcXnKT0R4Fs9EDam6YjWxt2OaxjF2Cu1Fud05vzylC6fy@vR28I@zi5sunQ1ed14PLjvvO5flmi68qQn9q8ODpzgioFTNqma8NFvftaqOl8ZjTS8P1ZcGGmQzjoWWxUnkTjS1qeo6DjVY5hXPxWlhengAvhu4vukB81PPTGgWWRpkMGVoRMinnscwuo9hzCJWpvp5dLGj0hkVPbrQI/Zl9HWEOo9gmI5iwQRx7ZDFgSpYSA40yEyicGgOvRkEVGM4vWAFYhYhxXzY4aAx8yYoMBlLDBKQjN0YzCFaaPJJowxmfA8@y0Ybi@4uLH0IselgtuIffybrGw8DwQDvFM9jmG9KlizxLFZ4JvERJgy9WKYTTMwocU1PUbgmhT4n8gjlg9NQNtCqUWT60AQnSy2f@SF2nSb03qAq/Z2DZ8/2D@Rpb@/ZQQN/d1ENTdLqfcSVa8VmXr5WIjZyaQCIEeGzenGtNqA2rddqZVC7F4VN65ZvarXz87KyobZpS7IJ73q@bl9ka0Q6LSCdFdcZwRfF8cyREN06x8NzE5s0YlwVNx@Km25xc51vcPShlsKiKIw0Px7p3G@U606p8/bt1dsGfMbjL/gnt/hJ9KWkKxsYnyrNZFpdF0xGLBlQGAbUfTXiRAtUUvo3Z9Ajf/X7fEbkKBh/Mqsh9VDZlFlpQsmVBqLH2ZIJ1u/GEh/YbdJYGLEkjQLOb0mdR7q3SB0vRGWWtFQ2xu66U8lOQ@jxMRzqsAteqChvOz92KX0oRiK6FDz@ecY/MagiUiIRRGj7RPfq9PKcaD9nEdYEEx4HvQz41rlEUEuAWoug1mWWPJoQNwe1CXQmQGeLoDMC8TSTsm6iVIp6RUTXc1E5pEUQnsJSUg5pE6R9MReUQ85eKTKRsBWG3gMb4PMn8g@51yO/jMcjtHwBWD8gN1Nbit0gTkx8c2mEin2EqJAMKTK39SK/zwO/cMZG/TxQUsoaLUgQMuTrdZE@O@12KKS9LIIYrzJku3a2u16AXRdh2WkBN@NAWY5NcJDlrNC/2xPaGAYcwg9w2Ofq8VLJzvGaFC4QJ4jEnSXQmrDPXSRM5wzRQWUoSsK3D6YBodGthYxquKThkLyIrZnMJirCIM7zqiK/rpRkGsQsyZGIgYvtP8JJW1YmmJaF9yAVqBS521ximumyjcrgtew4irJRNKqW6@LT9oBvMyuXynnZ2I3c3JyCZImkIGBBTp2jZRUudF3OCx22pZIrknJBZhwzvI4ytnvf4yq0/ibXrGMdang0CKMBOpWydqk@chiSpxOPiUphozKM3dGYl1iGgQDbTEyR8VgDCNGFuwm16AGOhinHr6yifUX4Dxk4g0rm894u5faFEA7OkoiHh@eRU6KbWHR2SqgsdxJk/3nOpFHbm/JLpqiDcFK86KQyB/3Prgo9@3ueijNAGTRuWXYnEJ10jV50XYGA4wtMEXyOmmGu@g/1QN@4I7z0Drmw@fUqWP6l9MjaqAzTQiH@V5HKS78QptUQ5Xbxu3ZtcvD7dgWCHqpLhZBUqoPPUozB/zGNlq9zmVALfv0rGZVfUuvcWgggMhYRXPTLMnheXcI7K/BCda5NGLRlDYT7FKFjV1oqkypjL23MtnCCQp47jflBpZmJlf7LIEV@qOT3GTrrWH6T6Tz35zwlomSROWsBHbX4E/yMggIaDT5Z1iAe42tCs0K8yOjhIii9dTMCvx@93EG0nvsGgTmPBqyZThG9KNrFh179YLAfTvhgEkdWHXMuTtZPSARGSG6laAN0qgvo3hJ04b4hi@LUI96c0Q792SvO0Ch4KWMFBZLyR0aPXhj9ooxFWp2@2hUkOcUHQVGgL9o/DSMxGSJ5mfRZNvyQ2019nmOM5EqHj2KNJLpsihN8b2dV0lh4GnSvuQ7CXbTToUJXdF7uRcTycsVl7MOJHB8X7tICU9R09XlDLEk4da1vwbPiFDiriq@i7ymrt6HMKHyv8doLkCBKJ8k3crgAp@zd4wNX/o4T19IaND4v0StcsD3Uiq8JXb4miL/AIZraC96twzSZpKSNqvKBybajeUzwdcGHxccxfSFKzMT4FrBHRLLGkcaFEZHOEQW9eO6JQZGjIvctfJQM8Uq45wApFRERTifiRSuOs@8ui7e1vFTUd4Hr46hAX1fwf80ke3XI/4GCNwut@Z2iFjr6N4mlD5Eu3@TECg9cKv8DxR@F6Gi7AeKbsYa8lYSfR/macni5xMtEul9rFKpLHD37c24f13HbRJWf1lBSbfrsnP7JheYMmRc@EteDwzlXWXxrFTp40Vhpdxzw/GDOYLkVFxsOXv2FbiKYWnZjnvH05Mw2lngayq8VcdOAwgQ2H@uo6HRJZbO/TFWZU5HNq2RzT0iSHD2cfFeIbDC6Qi8zfFGxaTl7oLEg9VlkYvHSA4/Km/@jkj9qCtlDqL@5Ey0ygxHTKHJlDNwBfh7iI6lX9JCkk5ZnO2lRvuUa9/l4U0zSnnzRcCX512LiWzitgMR1x9a5UNEcvq4hJdGMhIzNwPb4y3hBHN/gREhf/GMV/cxmHSq0QsWV0uA@CB@DIl1DlBvu89lP8tf0/wA) (runs all languages and generates an answer template, except COM file, which uses a really minimal x86 emulator I wrote. If you change the code so much that you hit an unimplemented instruction or interrupt, either implement it or drop a comment on one of my answers here)

Next answer must not exceed 360 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 2029 5835 2020 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh )X5  M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a  $*/main(){//\./*
00000050: 1b53 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 223e 3c3e  .SmiV.ZZ;ooo"><>
00000060: 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 220a 2369  ".#define S"".#i
00000070: 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364  fdef __OBJC__.#d
00000080: 6566 696e 6520 5322 2d65 7669 7463 656a  efine S"-evitcej
00000090: 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966 0a70 7269 6e74  bO".#endif.print
000000a0: 6628 2243 2253 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274  f("C"S)/*/import
000000b0: 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77   std.stdio;"D".w
000000c0: 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 0a3e 2242  rite/**/;}/*.>"B
000000d0: 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3822 3b22 4265 6675  efunge-98";"Befu
000000e0: 6e67 652d 3933 223b 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  nge-93";,,,,,,,,
000000f0: 2c2c 400a 202c 7756 6b4a 372d 3b6c 2865  ,,@. ,wVkJ7-;l(e
00000100: 5b4b 7421 6d5b 2a2f 2f2f e28e 9a6c 616f  [Kt!m[*///...lao
00000110: 6372 6168 43                             crahC
```

### Explanation

`vo` is a `jbe`, but FreeDOS explicitly sets the flags on entry to guarantee that this jump is never taken. This should also be the case on MS-DOS and DOSbox, but I can't test it right now.

`id /*` clobbers the stack pointer with `imul sp, [si+0x20], 0x2a2f`, but the result is always the same, since SI always points at the beginning of the code. The result of this multiplication is high enough to not interfere with the code during execution.

The rest is just standard printable x86 assembly. Here's the `yasm` source code:

```
org 0x100
bits 16

start:
    jbe short start+0x71
    imul sp, [si+0x20], 0x2a2f

    push patch+0x2020
    pop ax
    sub ax, 0x2040
    push ax
    pop si

    push 0x7e7e
    pop ax
    inc ax
    inc ax
    xor [si+0x20], al
    xor [si+0x22], al

    push msg+0x2040
    pop ax
    sub ax, 0x2040
    push ax
    pop dx

    push 0x2920
    pop ax
    xor ax, 0x2020

patch:
    db 0x4d, 0x21, 0x4d, 0x20 ; int 0x21 / int 0x20
msg:
    db "elif MOC SODeerF$"
```

Comment: Is there a termination point for the code, like a point past which new languages can be added?

Comment: I mean in the actual submission.

Comment: @Zacharý oh! The assembly code does not care about anything past the `$` on the first line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79637/discussion-between-zachary-and-niedzejkob).

Answer (score 7):

## 17. brain-flak, 613 bytes

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$+[*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@
noj6ZR42[jeeOCy(dm*///)]]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRpZctvI9Vu4Qn7akGwAIkCQlC1LFMnRbiuRLZUlzzimaA4INEhYWFhYJNIeT1UukAPkALlBvlM1R5mLOO91N0BwkT2VhLao7n5rv7Ub0MBKRl@/rpMDxyEWoUMrG4bWOUkjmI0jfzr0o5SkNEnJyIpDmiRkMCWvPXr8iX68jQbSOjmKfN8aJ5TIR5FDZWKFDpEP4mEW0DBNZJJQO/WiMCFuFJMBTVMaEzoZ09ijoU0lybZS0iE20Ep@SIyEDdlXdeCSdXJI3SwcUmN3S0qjzB6RcewBYwlEey6ZRhmxUPdcoE4C65aSJIsp7iKIHM@dEtCgOp6SJCLpCOSlIzoFEkq80PYzhzowwEXie@GtRO1RRIyQyBt1GVTjtKXVBq46UTK/uoWrSRQE1HC9CcKk8TQdReHWwur5wesXbw9enPTPXh@fvGvXpcO/Xp9cteUN9d4mht3CrWuyBLtmhiO@FQ4za0hV7bO0xuTJ62RjnkuVbNR1ssE4gYfAYbK0NgDfAkOmcSfK0nGWCgZic7/E9K6DvrBT6uS8F9eN0JfWwNKPiB2MCWdDciB58mQ1AKj20KKhtMb5/hRH4VBgVclLOnGyYNwE6GTikFw515PWFswDZlEXNlupa2Afoa5Bbn7eUDGIOBPt5md0JnNdJ4@VLxgtozQdJ03THHrpKBtU7Sgwr@PpWXoRgtepmcZTL43yMaVmYCUQq@Z9bI0hWhPgkHuCyJgRMpGZCmwszWDHAHAChxhxFrI4LgOvMBQAIc4gj8xonJosOPh3NR4sEXRaHUDPI4lRuF4yYl8Y0ov4R4DNsGwjtW1z4IUm/F6tzBHktB1ZfkEi5sVglYAfvQDw77ygyFUYV1MIgY7p0DszzHyfNDpP6hgb6BcBLvO4GHzEqnBHDVR3iPpNSFQs2pyvEZXXmAhgWTUXFsuMi2Kxk@9pUKwwW7iDgbe0pVmJWaBiJDDm@vxCUsvzMaMqW7tl@lMIl@OLK3J08Yq4nk9LDuNlooz8IvJX@HQY@cytSWzn41XGfxuWNziesgkxjCR12rs7MMgEwsN7fL5kmedGkLqeiV/AIV98mMP2dzgUy9tLPAax5YVuZt8WLPKF2WiJ6Dr@zqbT@IFNM56G61vz8kYWyDvE0UtLyCPGgSyxauES5SZsjWPaYZW4oxRlHEspNjEbC0w0pqGqIIaiVWNqOarWZPSqjX0pih3V1jrtrQb2Qz5r1RvPcWaTEJqqFyqtzhOF@tA6XeXJ@meO9GVP0WnotBVFmynUMpkqLRPVuglvwktW15o4VFgHFYVOEMg3YRdqG/GgKrKK9qjXvT676CH@azpJoUkn99CHgwwaOypDJzaFao61lvWQTn1r6wc@3KxvmfVak08qT2uaxhtMFZmtr@elHGeyhMUcVf0lAW5KYn4wCXxMpWRapkizqMbYXaE2mevrM0Pzjvv1613kOcTcHJ0/emfsk8sPo19/fbe/XzsmtWN5NOaL70ek8u4ZkV89ekWoD5Z/dXFEri6OKY1PNyrdTSjjXgit0zRvJGJWbqR6xcSxufmnq8D78U/v3@9FUST70Qt574d27fHVo3odFlqs8ErrDnXBfORKhrHnwoz0@xeHfz7q90swg955qU0/Di4AC5znuWK/KpTjK83cNL1gHMUpgYitwo8X7UGXqN7HXkrNzU1z74u52WpJ0BWu5b31T335UNb3O43KHoEjBXx6XXK3t763c6s/nzaMvX1dJy3A75RTcv3D@1rtxfqH/sZTo1OvdPTisy@F0cft92@eNrofKb04mqpOsAk20Hq93//@j9/@/fvf/uVbkR1bo6Pf/lmBT9do4a9Kp9fKh5VW6bvTAUhLACrVjgH/DaPaahn4qVZyAJ92jBwOqJ2OOvto@E/7/KX4z2c5pIB1VbXb6/ZynJ4GUw5kvwGKYACwdcYaF4ACcBgW4moce1@/teSdXYMOw8yl4Vv5qxtHAfnkewPCvbQpCW/B@YluP5Xctm8FA8ciYZMlfagr8aBIeslpDxQ8ad1MXBd/lIqrKlV2foU4VrTKQJmB@FipfowgKF31VMN6cgq1oMtLia7w2IcB7xwwKJ8elZ4m2W04ukAhSBJohOqufnxyen5wfXKsG68O3vV/Ojy7vsK1/quTV/3zkx9PzvWaxuNR5TuqDrafwtkb5Kl2NeelOlrFrrp@loxUTR8o@yZs0aEMC/aapLE3VpW2omlwW4BmZ/geHLMnO9sk8EIvsHxCg8y3UjzkL9wQICnxbF1cJ@6j@DYhIxpTHSvUvQcHBlzDsgpG9ZG9DtaPQechGWTDhDMBXCeiSahwFoID3gDGcTSwBv6UhFjF4NgPNQ7yEChmtwQGGlF/DALTkcBAAenIS4g1gB1a7MCtEyu5JQHN7wQ22h@KK4mgrEO@w69gKiooLIacARyZfJ9CMkp5@CTTRGKxxU7yUeQnIsDI2IpTz/IliWlS6iQ8skA@ceFoDLsaxlZA2sTNgy2gQQR1vU26r0GV3ub2s2db22K123i23YSfCqihClqtB7hiLDnUL8ZSTIcenm8TQPisnF0qTVKb1Gs1nShXZ6XJ0Ts2qdVOT3VpTTnGKcpGvMvZ@PgsHwPSQQnpsDzOCb5I0JOHXPTRKSyeWtAGAeOiPHlfnlyVJ5fFBE72WJRpHEexGiRDjdkNY92VT968uXjTJJ9h@Qv8Knb8KP4ia9Ia@KdKJ16q1jXOZEjTPrqhj/1NRU44ACWFfQsGXbRXr8euRQwF/I/bago9FDqhdpZicGUh7xKOYKKA4AU@pNImdVxNszhk/BbUuceTAarjR6DMgpbS2shbtSrYqQBttciORirEjyTpzcmLKwwf9BH3LjqPfR@yb3Aq9xQPBO7aHtK9PDg/RdrPuYdVzoT5QdPhqn5wDqAjDjqaBx2d58GjcnEz0DGCDjnocB50iCAWZkLWdZwJUS@R6HImqoAcIYSFsJBUQI4Rcnw2E1RADl9KIpCgFEb@He0HkRMHO8zqcaDD8hB2Pgesb6OZsSwlXpikVmhTFVGhjiAVkAFFbrZuHPSY4@fW6LBXOEpIWaEFCgKGbLzK04cHVyfo0m7uQfCXTvLZcT67nINdlmH5agk354BRDkWwn8cs1/@qy7UxTbJDHpOdHlOPpUq@Do2Tm4CvABIzFkdrky1mIr51xhAMpJOyJLjgQxggGnYtYFSDIbZLtCKUZtw2UiEGcp5lFdp1KSWzMKFpgYQMPCj/MVwkRWYSy7ahD2KCCpGV9gLTXJcnoAy0cdeVpLXypmqFLgFOt9k03@VCOi9udq3YbkGBsnhQILAkp87Q8gznui7GhUaeCCWXJBWCrCSh0I5yto1vceVaP8g1r1g7Kiz1o7gPRsWoXciPAgbk2dinPFPoUCcjbzhiKZZjAMCxUotHPOQAQDRubkQtW4ChQcixllXeXxn@OAfnUMF8VtuF3B4XwsB5EDH3sDhyZezEvLJjQOWxkwL7zzMmzVpjwppMWQdupGTeSDoD/c@minznW5ZKcoBOVLazvCcgnTCNVjZdiYDhc0zufIaaYy7bD/QA23hDaHo7TNisvXKWfyg88jIq3DSXiP@Vp4rUL7lp2UXFvlivXRkcrN8uQcBCdaEQkAp14OIPPvg/htFiOxcBNWfXPxJRRZNaZdaSA4Ex9@C8XRbBs@zi1lmCl7JzZcDAXlZAmE0BOvLETkVQ5ezFHvMpXJZrk@duc7ZgtHOxwn45pMwPlPw2Q3cVyweZzmJ/xlMgCha5sebQQYvv4OcU6NC4/9G2@8kIbhOqHUEjw4sLp/RXnRFYf/QLA@F4ZhsPn28KHk2y4nQK6GXRHlz06tv9rWjMDiZJbNch5pJ09QkJwQApdsnLAK5qHNpYgM71G9xRkvnImzHaxF@N8hkaBC9ELKcAUnbJ6OINo1eWMU@rkUdMbyApKN5zihJ9ef@TKOYnQyDXUZ/Fje@wfWOdZxhDMdLIBz4GEk0UxTHct/Msac5dDa4umQ7cXDjTiIEtukj3MqK@mHE5@2gsjo9zvbTEFDRdvt4gSxSOVesheJ6cHGdZ8WX0hrTcDUVEwX2N5V4IBHE2Th@I4RIco7fBDlzFPY63pRVo7LyEt3DOdkct3yY0cZtA/hwHaWq7rFqLt1ptoijswOQ48cwncLtgh8X7kedTxowf30J6D0j2KFaZMCTSGCKn59c9flBkqMB9Ay4lA2gJtwwgpAIiwHGF32j5cv50uNytRVNR3oZeAEcFfFzB3mmmjTop3iNCZ8Ex6ylKqaI/SCxsCHTFpCCWmOMy8WqXXQrB0E6T8GdlTdGVuJ2HxRhjeDHFdSTdqjVL2cWXnn2f24dV3NZB5ac1kFSbPDvFt8OwnQH1o3vkur0z4yqSb6VC27vNpXLHAM@3ZwwWS3G54EDrL1UTztR2mrOIxytnPrH51VA8aIRJk5ROYLNjHSadJqgc@oepjBkV7nmZbGYJQVKgR@NvChEFRpPwZgY3KjrR8wsaDbOAxhYkL17wML3ZXwCwS00pehD1kzdWYyscUhU9p4PjtuF7By5J3bKFBJ3YeT4TOyqmTOMeO96Ug7QrbjRMSfZYjD@FU0tITHconXMZzeCrClIaT1HIyAodn92M58SxCZwI8dUKZNFf6PQEE62UcXIW3obRfVima/J0g3lx9hP8Ve3r4uPC4kmhzS/f@WPCajL2oR4qNyGkKj71Q3jXgHK9DhRJFvDHnpT/YQJ//@WJR5kUPA2tHF8aSakVw6aBsXyQeM2dSrPZqDSfPt80An1PloraKMvc@7o973ZOzo4Ibf5yy9hq8CjwERPlNsWRGfbka3A@8ZqJwZD9rtfj@LNqiCU1ebz7rLLVyJ9o8xfqnJWsiz8B@A8)

Next answer must not exceed 796 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835 2022 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh +X5 "M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242b 5b2a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a  $+[*/main(){//\.
00000050: 202f 2b5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b53   /+\.1+///\./*.S
00000060: 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b  miV.ZZ;ooo"loG";
00000070: 3f3d 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f3c 223e 3c3e  ?=0%S!11ooo<"><>
00000080: 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 220a 2369  ".#define S"".#i
00000090: 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364  fdef __OBJC__.#d
000000a0: 6566 696e 6520 5322 2d65 7669 7463 656a  efine S"-evitcej
000000b0: 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966 0a70 7269 6e74  bO".#endif.print
000000c0: 6628 2243 2253 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274  f("C"S)/*/import
000000d0: 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77   std.stdio;"D".w
000000e0: 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 3c3c 0a20  rite/**/;}/*<<. 
000000f0: 2272 5422 3b23 7a5f 2242 222c 403e 322b  "rT";#z_"B",@>2+
00000100: 3b20 203e 2020 2020 5d5b 2076 3b23 3b38  ;  >    ][ v;#;8
00000110: 6b2c 3779 322d 3b40 2c2c 203c 3c3c 0a3e  k,7y2-;@,, <<<.>
00000120: 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3622 235e 5a30  "Befunge-96"#^Z0
00000130: 3047 235e 5f24 342d 3e31 2b3e 2c2c 2c2c  0G#^_$4->1+>,,,,
00000140: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 400a 6e6f 6a36 5a52 3432  ,,,,,,@.noj6ZR42
00000150: 5b6a 6565 4f43 7928 646d 2a2f 2f2f 295d  [jeeOCy(dm*///)]
00000160: 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372 6168  ]........laocrah
00000170: 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e  C..++++[-<+++++>
00000180: 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b  ]<[-<++++++<++++
00000190: 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b  +<+++++>>>]<<<++
000001a0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c  +++++.>-.>---.<<
000001b0: 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d  -----.++++++++.-
000001c0: 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b  ----.>--.>---.<+
000001d0: 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829  .>>>((((((((((()
000001e0: 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  ()()){}){}){}){}
000001f0: 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829  ()){})((()()()()
00000200: 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b  ){}){})[(([][]){
00000210: 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d  }){}()])([]()){}
00000220: 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d  )[]())(([[][]()]
00000230: 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d  ([]()((((([][][]
00000240: 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b  )){}{})[]){})))[
00000250: 5d28 2929 402c 6b61 2238 392d 6567 6e75  ]())@,ka"89-egnu
00000260: 6665 6e55 22                             fenU"
```

### How

I switched around some code to balance the brackets. I don't know how the brainflak works. Many thanks to @CatWizard (if that's still his username) <s>for the brainflak portion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45447490#45447490)</s>. Per @JoKing's comment, I changed it to outputting "brain-flak" reversed with [his script](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157666/55550).

Comment: There, it is now fixed.

Answer (score 6):

## 46. Curry, 3755 bytes

I tested this with different implementations (Sloth, KiCS2 and PAKCS) but only PAKCS (tested with version 2.0.2-b7) allowed me to get the BangPatterns to work:

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M eliF MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///opfzzfzzfzzfzzzfzzfzfzfffzffzzzzzffzfzzzffzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzfffzzfzfzzzfzffff⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
01 & && &&&     & {}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>](()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")";x--?y
 =y;y="yrruC";(!)=seq;main=let b!_=""in putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++y--?"lleksaH"
--N'Zi(Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*///∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejzaciiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaceeacewuuuweejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `eliF MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86
- `NOOPS` in Spoon
- `yrruC` in Curry

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbcttGls/CL8xLG1IMQCQIUbJliSIZ3WVnbUtjObbXJM0BgSYJCQQYXEjRilKpnSrXTtXWJDUP2cvDxtnandrLzFZNavKwtdkXz3vyD/qBmT/wntONGy@yncxAItB97n369OU0wZbud1@/nidbpkl0Qjt62HH0uyRwodZ37VHHdgMSUD8gXd1zqO@T1ojct@juc3py6raEebLj2rbe9ykRd1yTikR3TCJueZ2wR53AF4lPjcByHZ@0XY@0aBBQj9CzPvUs6hhUEAw9IFViAK9gO0T1WZHdCq02mSfbtB06HaqurwiBGxpd0vcsECyAaqtNRm5IdLQ9VpgnPf2UEj/0KLai55pWe0TAgkJ/RHyXBF3QF3TpCFgosRzDDk1qQgGBxLacU4EaXZeoDhEXiiKYxnkz0GWEmq4/Dl1BqO/2elRtW2fjuBuIe1To64HRFYT@KOi6zsps4gNP9/2SEHhENUwyfDwgZeYbxGObDbfXt2wK3cOaZoHtA@r54GHitsm2p1vObd04JTIr7tv6k7VVQj8KrYFug38UodVCRNvWgUYh5wIhvVPTgq6JwWrLDR3wCWCMPtHcfqAxXBfEaouFrj@b1JwJ9sE@1SKSr9Xl2jNdfb6lPm3UlTtOQDvU0@pFKK0sax2JLI5RB25M0vbcHit7uj1Nl2DfQrlsWb2@6wVkVw/0AlBxdKdrpD6DpvGGFArCRdZPVc2kA80JbZssV68XBUG4u3X/4MOtg73mnfu7e08qRWH7rx/uHVfEBXloQMexLlNEASKXBT@xdacT6h0qK@fCHOtqcZ4sjEspkIViniwwSTDKYNCJMe2D0HEsp0NYQF5fFuZaMGxBDwvGqhsG/TAQ5iBmwLsEnEzKhAMh7HhBtY1IGAvI82I@fyF@7NFBFceiEUBnRbpm4VTHFuZgtF0jRq@fSiQxnly/fiUOeDdwbDnCHNfw2HOhKZywQG7TMzPs9UuAPTszSdyWtiXMTTgZnCtPuCxXVJTESSqp/2xBxumEC1HqP8NhzXxWjWeNCxxD3SDo@yVN61hBN2wVYEhpD73RneDQgfFPtcAbWYEblynVeroPs5Y29PQ@zFu@EPcmEXdFIpo9CDEvdNicJWaQxzi@gcALYc5k44iNeH4veK0phmq5CuTx9MA42pbfZTecvibpd4CaURlqYBhay3I0eM42Zgfmb8PV7YQlqieFWQoeWT2gH1i9ZF6GciGAfp4YEhgA6PkInZVx2PoAV4ABVdHcDtp3RtzWSQQ0uFzVzcKYChBZ0CaAWcHJwrAWt6mVQJgv2q2WNdWkdDmZ4GIsUOb2fEwC3bJxiOVW1rP8@xAQu4fHZOfwHmnDRJzpML4kZIkPXHtGn3Zcm3Wr7xlxeZbzP3SyDeyPWIWoqh@YlfU1KIQRwdVtvDXlmVtqL2hbGt5AQgy8WsLqWyQk4NUpGXz@DI3TREQMSEtTTA@9tzQ68K5oNJOp4nw9po@tWumyyINta4wR5lKRP6aE3tb9U2rbbBCDKFaZInrO@J/PYKc998Sa7H4G5PdZ3R6pzG0D5EjH7ZLjj@tXn2Rx0yM9l8OBlsvhQDPgEQ8wo99PB1ZUyTLu9dzActyeZbgOSIAJHBfM@4e7e82jrYe3K3VRC31Ps62W5oDIJmxAQpv6dRElIiRpXyJmrFI4mTb2lPnudIbvTN4t5qxuSaPknSP8DZGzZVvG@DytI0SDBYN6fY/CfdZs/dNQN3@MHR@lfFMy19djOevrGiz5NBjhfYZuNO7H6E74pmT6o17LhYaT7MDtuY4brV2tNn4K9IyzzloCGDXbugPV2FII9R9urR9zTdsK6zP1Y0m8pgWQBNBA86hNdZ9G0OlVmfaDH2VL/yrH7eMuz7XMWFg7qieFKQ62yR@LuA5C@H1WrOl2vztzJo0QpGA5uJ2CzebYVLB1/9HWMXClo9PQnYHuswE8azw6eg/cB2leDIpVxgjNtHwwILRsM4UlXFMT4MDCyfNEH@iwltrQOsiButE8ATjCblPbDmDB3USUMcFizJ@MbaC2YU7RtUeYicCsxp4zYjEzYTKSWeuFbdOsS6EaP6dXxDSdEuO1LZPqZJYYdWs65voun1Jxo3r/8PDoWOQJH8eQXggJdouyRBt20z3dCXXbHpEhbFBn7Vbv6R6MZN@kB5Seaj7KyBNIr/uYJBw7Lux1O/ue2xmLhdDzRrENI88Ld2IbGObdbBgOhxBpkMn39MA6LYSOpZ5a1C6YVPukr58aPkyaJj0rdIOenVq0fe9QhLQXd@BtItWdMkyqVZYjVaUkG8ZsBo8IDNy0u33qyBJSSErBo7opKyXGLxuY9bueKRtKtbKyjKcNvFYuLt/CmgFLUQAypHL1@oJEbZ@StnR9/pxTXWxIeeqYFUmCxCG2qKwxW8oa2lV36s4RSxZKWJTYAUWUPUQMYt2pQcJALEg1WJpwrVF7eOewgfT36VlAdMcfUo@7FK2hZwYFn2ICw9K7anFl5X1eXCyuaMWlEq/kbiwpCs/9Cihsfj7Oj7AmCpghoakfY1oL2e8zjcClSRnfMkNKSYfh4QWMBG1@PvU0P9B4/XqAU5O2qJ6rKpnvPrj2RN0kR8@6n3zyZHNzaZcs7YrdAQc@7ZLck5tEvHftHqG2tU/uHe6Q48NdSr39hYscXLVFTYNx1H7@PPnnD/hr4@c5XljKPNjf86kKMqRQuC5fvrj86sW73OsC0XJkHh6wnaM4LUFCK2MA4ckOgQ52DW1hQYOFRWEp7kapXJb2DvclMl@t1oViDppBpq7DuqAtkp90OsZBz3r0k6dPN1zXFW33QNx4v7L03vG1YhEAZZbACfMmbeOafYz5Gb80bUuYt9qAIM2m0bdDHz@aZgukLSsbWVWaZgEpP5YqG7DttdyqphkZqbkcyNU0KkCQB1lzQTWEttVOQPVCqvVw@4OdZjNrnApzb2DQD1qHMaMAo95yZOWch5N8rGiLWgSKjk/AoAIzagNy38LQswKqLS5qGxfa4kVZqBIyGD6Gi90eD7Ey/OGFx8P0SoTFj@SZLY1XxuBXQN4R9Hg4C/g4se0K1OOrUfwS1tfXCf@kRSwNytUluIpF/BcGhEBIpSlRPr5ujVbUQZlsosvnnx0MpkJ2My9ui03YKQPPpgCAQbnWFBuZ9LeaCMsvfbxZRprqfDmb@lXJs8HCARiDdjBC8da6SjtO2KbbImlOD5QBiwFGujnPQRke76HYHMwTFLlULFcF8sarXC2iJw4WBpxwfjM/dm3OZySbevhTsckYUo4rr2xDAsdKWYH32mBMz1skjV8ZqX16DO4f2/eON2Bz/q2yoesHInQe9OW@mBdD@DjwMeATwMeFjwUfUyxXiQcrgukOHRIMXVaxaRuXJ0pGsAVyhyTsk45HqcOpZgKRDSBBF0Cs4lmdbsAkRvRZXlZu2SHlqibksEJG/TtQv8HydxKS8KUSWUt@sO3oA7BlprtmC/izPMeGO4s/HoTFsRLes7UsxbvQT9NNy8ngilfIL75J4tJbNL6D3hhTTO/JI1ua@iQEkQ85cZHXiilvRJbisjwZkh/8jBXFKme0rzjF8yP1RU0VliDFwSTnOnzwuk7OLxqXv/ynP37761f/Y@uu4endnVf/dfnF16@Sv8u/@5vLF//@3e/g9ocv4ZbCLl98DpBf/OvlF99evvgVu39@@Yt/wzLDf/9zLEb/jDmtff9pphbBXn31hy9ffZVUv/v9DEZG98041/cvkPobEMnUjouJSD4FY774Oib4/uevvolIoPbd79Ly959CGQjZ/1iRCQDi3zOFMZzDvsHGf/Htq69e/W@uprKNrVrGR67aKMfFXDlzr1YBU44QuUJVhX9VLZTLKl6FXIzg1aoa44EUOGVZif@UclWOnufy@UVNVhoIwrIS1y@gXK5eMMpzhMjl8ws5vbggIIr/eU1O1ESImizXGrVGTNNQoMqR7AlYRKN8vDPRCAAOoGFUSKtw6ioz6xwEleXx6y9kTo0ZoSACiJIar7M/xjOuM6u4xomZofI5US@aFVERN85U9f2RQCqjjVFF5BnxhnxNqfj0ow3c9VZsChnxNSAWISXth8Fx4C3IonhN9B2PBoF@1HH07Zyo5HIjECXaNj319duioKr3paeW/PDEWqtsatu9D5eVmtooV@u1OtzqGty0ek2DW7mKf7zMwOwR/9XrDY2BEI3Fer2gNXxMtS7/9h@Ptx7d39r54/99/qcvf/Ub68TtUSxc/vNXf/ryH36bPcuF@teXn/3n5We/ufzsPzbzp7q4Fm9TnA99vHS8aHL1M2XD8uPaiRVdJ3TqOnmuG1b2QhrdYJ9hGIbDiP1kkgSuU/6ABODy5aeXL7@4fPn3ly9/efkv8P9r/H/53@Jr/G6XPLetFuGJyKIQJSSY563eENoVW@@1TJ04JXZ24OQlr5WcHQhmpSXhAX/9rN3Gj5Rry1KBnVRCNiwpuZaUonhZKpy4kPm05X0FjyX2Iduq8ROJvMQzaCjwr3ygkP0uH6rRyZXUUASjgl/Ze9T33daJvJ7f3du/u/Vwbzev3tt60ny8fefhMcKa9/buNe/uPdq7m19SeD4v87YVWqs3qIOaZaMQy5JNJWcU2pBFdmUl35I2NWisSRkVtNoPPKsvSxVJUV7Pk93DY9W2Tik5W1slPcuxerpNaC@09QDfyZh4ocNqs1chkrc/hq536pMu9WgeTzyGlm0zGJ7TgHttFJ@HfvDw1Im0wo7PhQCt6VLfkbiISAK@sAFZeEtv2SPi4KlI4BJ6FkACChzpSx0M1aV2nx9AcQpUEHQtn@gtaKHOvlvPE90/JT0av8JhYE84gY@vQ@BmEB69UXQiA0CHCzC6OgxX2JgLcSD5I19gUcZPbV3bj0KN9HUvsHRbEJglmaMpHmOgn7RLwhy0quPpPVIh7TjserTneiOA1O6DKY3F1Zs3V1YjaG355moJPjkwQ454lQbQRmXBpHZSFjzasfBLaB8IzqU7R1KJLJ3BZiBPpOM7mcrOE1ZZWtrfzwtz0i5WUTfSHaXl3TtxGYi2Yh4mYTvDsh2zXAhtW@9w5Tv7ANzXbR8pDrOVp9nKcbZylFQuBAEPJKjnuZ7c8zsK8xxGe1vce/Dg8EGJnAP4Ah5Jm695F6IizEEPFeiZFchFhQvp0KCJHdHEEzMZJWEBjIw8nAiooccaDfYOAyOBCMBmlSI7JEjTjDDA8MLTXDwhMSMhEiiekENyFVJEaBB6DpM3Yc4QzxrRHNsFYyasFOa61ixoJE4GbLlM1hSSI7YrCA/2Do4xgLCXeP9i97H7NrtDt/Ke4qHAO7eBfLe37u4j73ncxzIXwvpByZN5snUXUDsctTOO2rkbh4/M1aWoXURtc9T2OGobUSzQIl0PvTBSdRuZjlJVCWYHMSyII00JZhcxu3dSRQlm@7YQBRJMhq49YF9Ger015nWvlwdwB1o@hiyuoptxYvItxw90x6AyksJMglzABhyx22per8E6fgxGO42koyItM6xARSCQlWf19PbW8R52aS3uQeivPIlru3HtaAx3lMXF0AxtLAGjHKbBZhyz3P7jGrdG08gaeY@sNZh5bKjEcFhEuQs4BIiYszhZhawwF/GmM4HgoDzJahLm8LAdyXDdAkFLUMSlE70IkzM2G7mQAiWnowr9OjUkQ8enQUKEAixYADxqBNHIJLphwEqIAzRSmatMCI1tuQ7GnOFJsiDMZRu1lNjSw@oqq8atnBjOk42dS5qbcKAuHhSIzOgpMrJ4hHNbJ@NCgSSOGzmlKVGk@z6FBSkWu/wmqdzqK6XGM9aaDKCm6zXBqRi1E@MjwQF72LcpHym0kyddq9NlQyymAISpBzqPeBgDgFG4u5E06wFGBiHHFq1s@7L492J0jI2Ep3N7pLfBlTB0HESse1gctUVci/nMjgEVx04A4s9TIaWl5TO2yGRt4E7yx52UZ6g/21Wubb7JU36MyBOZtSxeE5Avco2SdV2GgdFzSt75jDSmnPYf2AG@sTqw6K0xZenyykW@U3jE02jUTWMD8Uf1VDL0M9003UVJu9haOzM42Ho7hQEPFSODgDUyB7@yBPK/XBhNLudRQI359V0iKlmkZrk104EgmPfguF8m0eno4t6ZwmdG58yAgbbMwDCfArZrRS2NgioWH7UxrpIqKLnVLqUAtRKrjfwXY7LywMg3C2zPEnml0DT2U5kRYSQidtYYOVjxFvqYAzvUa54YRtPvQj4hQ0puWpi6cE571h6BrY924iAsp76x8CXFSEaJzNidAnlWtQWpXnG1ueL22cbE94wixJwfzN4hIRowSSv5NIBQhWOXJ7Bj6w22yA9tlM0ELeJjObuHBsUTEcs5gJUlGTXMMBpZHeO8CrnG7AaWhOMp58jwZ9t/5np8ZwjsebRnsuFrrN04zzOKTlRSyDNeBhYlmhT7kHHHo6Q0lhocHzEbuLuwphAVl@hkuGcJ85MjLhbv9qPt49hamhEKlk6nNygSleOsdRU@HpycZtrwafJlYXo1jCIK8jU29vAVOS/sB1fEcAaP0bvMNlxJHseXpRlkbL@EeTgXuyZnswklyiZQPqdBnqV1NltHr71XiCSxDZNpemmfQHbBNovDLv6CAoXx7ZtDh0BkdD2ZKUMmhRFyfp7u8Y0iIwXpC5CUtGBJOGWISCsQAh4hPKPl4Ph9k@xqHS0q0oeO1YOtAh5YsB@hBMtFkvxoAFYWLLM1RcrM6FcyRz4EvqSSMAus48LotzgsKQRHmyXCz81K0arE/dxJyhjDk0M8j6wrS6XM6OKgm2@X9myWtHkw@cYSaFo6u7mPP@eB5rSo7Q5R6upaKjUafDMNWl0vTU13DHFrNRUwORVnJxxY@jOzCRdqmKU04jHljCsGTw2jQ0eolEhmB5Zu63DQKRGXSd@ZS025sM3TbKknIpaE3O2/UUk0wSgCZmbsZa18nKBRJ@xRT4fBiwkeDm/2ky2W1GSiB0mfW33Z050OlbHn8tBxq3BfgySplvVQxBe1PK5FLUqqzOIG295kg7QWZTTMSHYwxs/h5AwRsx2mzrERzfCzJqTAG6GSru6YNsuMx9SxCuwI8WUtGEV/RUd7ONAyI04MnVMHv7vN8JX4cIN6sveL5Mt49HroWR3L0W2SDFWd@bA1IpvpqStsE6P3tdBe/E1AAfaAximY0kUvs5f@dK24euvWjZvajbXi@lq0XrStsyY7e5aREzIP9g5snthOBed5cKpA8EjVdtJNLX5hCHWYxVRVAgfLeALJGdmSpSxKREI@FFlTl9l@zyEw7UL@Gfb4ISxlh7NYZi8DW@xo1ae4L4HQg70FvheHQpIZWRSxysIub4zHW6Scm@ZX@Kt66soyqyOHjfSoqBS9M4FNAqttBbZIVslXGY9dsxoJWzon48Tuv7d@M7eyrKAJ0ZoW/dRo6lQ3PtDl7c8c5xb8vg2rllR3JOZ9O3IQrKqTvmFdkvUM@3Fh6haBtxi9suVbpbVcqbScK924taj28huiEDpDnU3qgF8q6ga1Tty@LyvnF7VGuZovqDkRVYJQGCH4Ax6fT/9t6lEy1IgLGI@rl@N3c/NkK3pX@Dr/yZu6b@unitC1@xgK16HHmYGVK2IKmuxD36ZhI0XfkPT0vhxNNgae1BEpBzKVGuvjuCWNPGu@otSWS403K4IdmmMq0fuiMv8VFe97EZJhZK2VlnF7AmQojdFHIIYFmKK8Xl3Jr94yVleEcvI@DQQNZT9Fi0MApkT88ST0F2ZYkN4phL0waroZLrwMUlZJ94AG@DMq0p3E4kRlELc9AcdLuiYRtTpLYVeZQd5E4k6fyEbJVwRVVfF9qh9qfmooqVYrKK5AZJT3/w)

Next answer must not exceed 4881 bytes.

### Explanation

As with the Haskell one the code defines the `(/*-)` operator, then it goes on to define the operator `(--?)` which only Haskell recognizes, Curry treats everything after the `x` as comment:

```
void /*-{- ...
-}_=")";x--?y
```

So we define `x --? y = y` for Haskell and then the expression (needs to be at the end of a line) `"yrruC"--?"lleksaH"` will evaluate to the right string in each language:

```
 =y;y="yrruC";(!)=seq;main=let b!_=""in putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++y--?"lleksaH"
```

The above code makes sure that the `-XBangPatterns` flag is still recognized, I had to rewrite that a little to make sure Curry works well with it.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6946 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M eliF MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 7066 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a7a 667a 7a7a  /opfzzfzzfzzfzzz
00000060: 667a 7a66 7a66 7a66 6666 7a66 667a 7a7a  fzzfzfzfffzffzzz
00000070: 7a7a 6666 7a66 7a7a 7a66 667a 667a 7a7a  zzffzfzzzffzfzzz
00000080: 667a 667a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a7a 7a66 7a66  fzfzfzzfzfzzzfzf
00000090: 7a66 7a7a 667a 667a 6666 667a 7a66 7a66  zfzzfzfzfffzzfzf
000000a0: 7a7a 7a66 7a66 6666 66e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  zzzfzffff.......
000000b0: a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1  ................
000000c0: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086  ................
000000d0: e2a1 865c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  ...\. /+ #\. bas
000000e0: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
000000f0: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000100: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000110: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
00000130: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
00000140: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
00000150: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
00000160: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
00000170: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000180: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000190: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
000001a0: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
000001b0: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
000001c0: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
000001d0: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
000001e0: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
000001f0: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000200: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000210: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
00000220: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
00000230: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
00000240: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
00000250: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
00000260: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
00000270: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000280: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000290: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
000002a0: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
000002c0: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000300: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000320: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
00000330: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
00000340: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000350: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
00000360: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000370: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000380: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000390: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
000003a0: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
000003b0: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
000003c0: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
000003e0: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
000003f0: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000400: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000410: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
00000420: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
00000440: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
00000450: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
00000470: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000480: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
000004a0: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
000004b0: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
000004c0: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
000004d0: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000500: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000510: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
00000560: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
00000570: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000580: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000590: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005a0: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22   <>"v"@. @,"F","
000005b0: 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22  u","n","c","t","
000005c0: 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564  o","i","d"<> red
000005d0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
000005e0: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
000005f0: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000600: 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  ow up green down
00000610: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
00000620: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
00000630: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
00000640: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
00000650: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77  een down red dow
00000660: 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  n one yellow dow
00000670: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000680: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000690: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
000006a0: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
000006b0: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
000006c0: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
000006d0: 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77  left one red dow
000006e0: 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  n three yellow d
000006f0: 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  own yellow down 
00000700: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000710: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20  down red up two 
00000720: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  green down yello
00000730: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
00000740: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075   blue left red u
00000750: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
00000760: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
00000770: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000780: 7565 206c 6566 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030  ue left 00011100
00000790: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
000007b0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
000007c0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
000007e0: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030  1000100010000000
00000800: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000810: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000110000100010
00000820: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030  0010000010001100
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000840: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000850: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000860: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000870: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000880: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000890: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030  0000110000110000
000008a0: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030  0110000010011000
000008b0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010001000100010
000008c0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031  0010000001001101
000008d0: 3131 3030 3030 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131  1100000011001111
000008e0: 3030 3031 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030  0001100110000000
000008f0: 3130 3031 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030  1001110011110000
00000900: 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  1101110000010000
00000910: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000920: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000930: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000940: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031  0001000110001101
00000950: 3131 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  1110001000100010
00000960: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031  0000100010100001
00000970: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0000000100010000
00000980: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000990: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000009a0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000009b0: 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 0a30 3120 2620  0000100110.01 & 
000009c0: 2626 2026 2626 2020 2020 2026 207b 7d5d  && &&&     & {}]
000009d0: e28e 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63 7261 6843  ........laocrahC
000009e0: c2ab e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2e2  ................
000009f0: 8c82 e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f e286 a8c2  ................
00000a00: b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690 c39f e289  ................
00000a10: a4e2 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286 90e2 89a5  ................
00000a20: e286 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a30: 92e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000a40: 8692 e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a50: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2  ................
00000a60: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000a70: c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a80: a8c2 b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a90: a1cf 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
00000aa0: c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000ab0: 86a8 c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2 8c82 e286  ................
00000ac0: a8c2 a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000ad0: a1ce b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80c2  ................
00000ae0: a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 e296 b2e2  ................
00000af0: 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb4  ................
00000b00: c2a1 cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000b10: c2a1 ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1 c2bb 2b5b  ..............+[
00000b20: 2d2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c  -++++[-<+++++>]<
00000b30: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c  [-<++++++<+++++<
00000b40: 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b  +++++>>>]<<<++++
00000b50: 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d  +++.>-.>---.<<--
00000b60: 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d  ---.++++++++.---
00000b70: 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e  --.>--.>---.<+.>
00000b80: 3e3e 5d28 2829 2829 2829 2829 2829 293c  >>](()()()()())<
00000b90: 3e28 2829 2829 293c 3e7b 287b 7d5b 2829  >(()())<>{({}[()
00000ba0: 5d29 3c3e 287b 287b 7d29 287b 7d5b 2829  ])<>({({})({}[()
00000bb0: 5d29 7d7b 7d29 3c3e 7d3c 3e28 2829 7b5b  ])}{})<>}<>((){[
00000bc0: 2829 5d28 3c7b 7d28 2828 2828 2828 2828  ()](<{}(((((((((
00000bd0: 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  (()()()){}){}){}
00000be0: 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928  ){}()){})((()()(
00000bf0: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b  )()){}){})[(([][
00000c00: 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829  ]){}){}()])([]()
00000c10: 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d  ){})[]())(([[][]
00000c20: 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b  ()]([]()((((([][
00000c30: 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29  ][])){}{})[]){})
00000c40: 2929 5b5d 2829 293e 297d 7b7d 297b 7b7d  ))[]())>)}{}){{}
00000c50: 283c 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  (<((((((((((((((
00000c60: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29  ()()()){}){}){})
00000c70: 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829  {}()){})((()()()
00000c80: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d  ()){}){})[(([][]
00000c90: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929  ){}){}()])([]())
00000ca0: 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 5b5b 5d28 2928 2928  {})[]())[[]()()(
00000cb0: 295d 295b 5d29 5b5b 5d28 2928 2928 2928  )])[])[[]()()()(
00000cc0: 295d 295b 5d5b 5d5b 5d5b 2829 5d29 2828  )])[][][][()])((
00000cd0: 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d28 2929  ((((()()()){}())
00000ce0: 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2829 2829 5d29  {}){}){})[()()])
00000cf0: 3e29 7d7b 7d28 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b  >)}{}({ -}_=")";
00000d00: 782d 2d3f 790a 203d 793b 793d 2279 7272  x--?y. =y;y="yrr
00000d10: 7543 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e  uC";(!)=seq;main
00000d20: 3d6c 6574 2062 215f 3d22 2269 6e20 7075  =let b!_=""in pu
00000d30: 7453 7472 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474  tStr$(""!"snrett
00000d40: 6150 676e 6142 2b22 292b 2b79 2d2d 3f22  aPgnaB+")++y--?"
00000d50: 6c6c 656b 7361 4822 0a2d 2d4e 275a 6928  lleksaH".--N'Zi(
00000d60: 546a 6938 3d40 2f42 6d55 3229 5b2d 5d3c  Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]<
00000d70: 3e5c 5b5c 3c3e 5c5c 2f3c 3e5c 2f5c 5b2f  >\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/
00000d80: 5c2f 5c3c 3e3c 3e3c 3e5c 5b2f 5c2f 5c2f  \/\<><><>\[/\/\/
00000d90: 3c3e 5c2f 2f5c 2f3c 3e3c 3e3c 3e3c 3e3c  <>\//\/<><><><><
00000da0: 3e5c 5c5d 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f 2f5c 2f5c 5d2f  >\\]/\//\//\/\]/
00000db0: 5c2f 5c5c 2e2f 5d73 2a2f 2f2f e288 9953  \/\\./]s*///...S
00000dc0: 4156 4e41 43ef bd90 f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d  AVNAC.......ijom
00000dd0: 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74  e...........Emot
00000de0: 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2  inomicon........
00000df0: 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e  .....@,ka"89-egn
00000e00: 7566 656e 5573 7373 7373 6161 6161 6165  ufenUsssssaaaaae
00000e10: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6570 6165 6565 6565  eeeeeeeeepaeeeee
00000e20: 6565 6565 6563 6973 6165 6565 6565 6565  eeeeecisaeeeeeee
00000e30: 6a69 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565 6565 6565  jiiiiiiiijeeeeee
00000e40: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6a7a 6163  eeeeeeeeeeeejzac
00000e50: 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565  iiiiiiiiiiiiijee
00000e60: 6561 6365 6561 6365 7775 7575 7765 656a  eaceeacewuuuweej
00000e70: 6969 6969 6a69 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969  iiiijiiiiiiiiiii
00000e80: 6a65 6565 6161 6161 6b65 6561 6161 6177  jeeeaaaakeeaaaaw
00000e90: 7677 e2a0 80e2 a096 e2a0 97e2 a08e e2a2  vw..............
00000ea0: 8ee2 a2a6 e2a2 a6e2 a0ae 22              .........."
```

Answer (score 5):

## 12. Unefunge-98, 320 bytes

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh )X5  M!M elif MOC SODeerF$*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
>"Befunge-98";5-;,,,,,,,,,,@
nq]j\m7-;l(e[Kagd-*///⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRnbUttI9hn9wryciEwkgW3ZEAgYzASMSdiBQMVkNhtwPLLUshV08eoC9mQyVfsD@wH7AfsH@7xV8ynzI9lzuluybJzM1O6mKqa7z/3ap@2BlYw@f16FQ8cBC9jQyoahdQZphLtx5E@HfpRCypIURlYcsiSBwRReeez4J/bhNhooq9COfN8aJwzUduQwFazQAfUwHmYBC9NEhYTZqReFCbhRDAOWpiwGNhmz2GOhzRTFtlI4ABtpFT@EasKX/KM2cGEVjpibhUNW3d1U0iizRzCOPWSsoGjPhWmUgUW65wIrEFi3DJIsZmRFEDmeOwXUoDaeQhJBOkJ56YhNkYSBF9p@5jAHF3QIvhfeKsweRVANQX3cUFE1QVs63aBTJ0roVDk7fPXizeGLTv/01XHnbauhHP3lqtNtqY/1exuq9j4ZYqgK2sDdAL4VDjNryHTjo7LCeaqr8HieSw0eNyrwmHNCf6P7VWXl4s3V5ZsrYjzAmCFrrgmyXum8vey0rzrHBBMcUfGfY3ZHQPTRNR4IahUetXCTE6jQ2yOzQ2VFqtLBwNgp@qPAqcAQMyCnJ8SJl0JDWXE9ZWXBeJSvL5iy3jBIC8G9Cjc/Sk43P5LLuYMP8oh@opiO0nScNE1z6KWjbFCzo8C8iqen6UWIsWFmGk@9NMrXjJmBlWBGmfexNcacSpBD7mFQKW9VULlwvlZmMDRedQIHqnEW8mwrA7tREGAqq3GG2W5G49RM6ER81uLBA4KD/QNEH0/TURRuCgrXS0b8gxJvEb@N2BzLrqa2bQ680MS/y5VpY@XZkeUXJHJfLJYJ@MELEP/OC4qKwnUtDcZwYDrszgwz34eNgycNePIEqAQluMzjYvCBaveOVUndIek3gag4tAXfalQ@4yKQZc1cOCwzLkp6J7dpUJxwX7iDgffApFkjWKDiJLgW@vwMqeX5VB/rm7tl@hNMl@OLLrQvzsH1fFYKmCjmMvKLyF8S02Hk87AmsZ2vlzn/TVg2cDzlG6hWk9Rp7e7gIpMIklLhBeCCdhPuj2N2wJvGgabksqnWqXvaVDPRmIW6RhiaUYuZ5ehGk9PrNjXEKHZ02zhobW5QIxa7/cbGM9rZEGIte6G2f/BEYz72bFd7svpRIH3a0yosdFqahgWbK7RvclX2TVLrJrwJL3mpNmmp8dYta1cSqDfhNZYrYIsQRfqod311etEj/FdskuLtkNzjBRBkeKOQMmxiM2o32Dh4uztobG5@J5ZrjU2zUW@KzfrTumGIXlgjZqur8JJNnCwY005VJhOHO/PnBLlpifneBPxnaiXXckWaRYOhto7lZq6uzhwtWv3nz3eR54C5Njp79Lb6HC7fj3755e3z5/VjqB@ro7E4fDcC4@0WwPmjc2A@ev78og3di2PG4pPHa9iXvBB7vGneKGCu3yiNdZPW5to33cD74Zt37/aiKFL96IW6912r/m33UaNBB5R0yqrDXPQddFVcey7uoN@/OPpTu98vwarszktt9mFwgVgYOc@VxurYXrqGuWZ6wTiKU8C0q@F/L9rDrle7j72UmWtr5t4nc005KBfj3lZ1r1L8e66Ef@19uAmeVfd8nV1/bw2d6hoa8dvf//Hrv3/72798K7Jja9T@9Z/PK7eWurNbZcMwc1n4Rv3sxlEAP/neAIQOa4rUBe8utv1UcVu@FQwcC8Imz@ewosWDIp8VpzXQ6Ja7mbgu/dfWXV2r8ZkAQ6QZ6wNtDiSqQZ7yExHJ@TNR5Zqh2C28VjCjkwSblL5bOe6cnB3SXVc9P3zb//PR6VWXzvrnnfP@WeeHzlmlbgjf6kL/2mD7KU4vKFW3azkv3THW7ZrrZ8lINyoD7bmJBjmMY6FlSRp7Y11raYaB8xY2oqrv4aAy2dmGwAu9wPKBBZlvpTQmLcxYmF00nRQD2X0U3yYwYjGrUKnde9jM6Yz6A7rQJ/YV9HWMOg9hkA0TwQRxnYgloSZYSA40Q43jaGAN/CmEVI44OGGxYk4hxWzO4qAR88coMB1JDBKQjrwErAFaaPEhpwJWcgsBy6cqm65N7BIQYX/C3MU/wVS2AjwMBQO8znyfYSoqebIk00ThmcSnpyjyE5lOMLbi1LN8ReGalFqiyCOUD25TWUGrhrEVQAvcPLUCFkTYoFpw/QpV6a1tb21tbsvT642t7Sb@X0c1dElr9BBXrhWH@cVaidnQo9kjQYSP2uml1oT6pFGvV0DrnpY27bd8U6@fnFSUFe2YtiSb8C5n6@PTfI1IhyWko/I6J/ikuL41FKLbJ3h4YmE/R4yL8uZdedMtby6LDU5d1GBYHEexHiRDg/uNct1VO69fX7xuwkc8/oR/CosfxZ9UQ1nB@NRoHNQbhmAyZGmfwtCnRq0TJ1qgktK/BYNr8levx8dTjoLxJ7OaUg@NTZidpZRcWSg6niOZYP2uLPCB9RZNpDFLszjk/BbUuacrjtTxI1RmQUtlZeQtO5XsdITu78OOAevgR4ryuvOiS@lDMRLRpeDxzyP@iUEVkRKJIELbI7qXh2cnRPsxj7AumPA4GBV87ByeIagtQO15UPssTx5diJuBjgl0JEBH86AjAvE0k7Ku4kyKeklElzNRBaRNEJ7CUlIBOSbI8elMUAE5eqnIRMJWGPl3rI8vrzjY4V6PgwoeD9HyOWBjm9xMbSnxwiS18DmoEyr2EaJCMqTI3XYdBz0e@LkzNuwVgZJSlmhBgpAhXy@L9NFht0Mhvc4jiPGqQL47zneXc7DLMiw/LeHmHCjLsQn285wV@nevhTamCTvwLez0uHq8VPJzvCaFC8QJInFnCbQWbHIXCdM5Q3RQBcqS8NmFaUBodGshozouaY4kL2JrJrOJijCI86yqyK8PSjILE5YWSMTAw/Yf45AvKxMs28Z7kApUilxvLTDNdXmCyuC17LqKslI2ql7oEtB2m29zKxfKedHYlcLcgoJkiaQgYElOg6PlFS50XcwLA55IJR9IKgRZScLwOsrZbnyNq9D6i1zzjrWj41E/ivvoVMrahfooYEiejX0mKoUNKzDyhiNeYjkGAhwrtUTGYw0gxBDuJtSyBzgaphy/ssr2leHf5uAcKpnPeruU2xNCODhPIh4enkeuSjex6OyUUHnupMj@44xJs74x4ZdMWQfhpGTeSRUO@p9dFfnO1zyV5IAK6Nyy/E4gOukao@y6EgHHF5gi@Bw1x3zoP9QDfeMN8dLb4cJm16tg@YfSI2@jMkxzhfhfRaoo/VKYHoaosIvftUuTg9@3DyDooYZUCEmlOviCxRj8H9No8TqXCTXn1z@SUcUltcytpQAiYxHBeb8sgmfVJbzzAF6qzqUJg7YsgXCfInTkSUtlUuXspY35Fg5QyDO3OTuotnKx0n85pMwPlfw6Q3cZyy8yneX@jKdElCxyZ82hoxa/g59TUEDj/gfb7icjfE3odoQXGT1cBKW/bEbg96NfOIjWM9949N2T5NGEJdMpopdFe/jQa2z3N6MxH0yS2G5gziXp8gmJwAgprBRtgE4NAd1YgM7dN2RRkvnEmzNaoz8b5RkaBS9krKBAUv7IuKYXRq8sY57WoG@VBUlB8U5QlOjL9k@iWEyGSF4hfRYN3@F2U5/nGEO5MuC9WCOJIZviGN/beZU0554G3Uuug3AX7Qyo0hVdlHsZsbJYcTn7aCzHx7m7tMQUNX34vCGWJJy61pfgeXEKnIeKP0TfUB7ehjKj8L3Gay9Egjgbp1/I4RKcsneDD1zFO05cS0vQ@LxEr3DBdkcvvyYM@Zog/gKHaOq7vFtHWTrOSBtN4wOT48SzmODrgg@L9yPPZ5yZGN9Cdo9I9ijWuTAiMjiioBfPPTEoclTk/hgfJQO8Em45QEpFRITTiXjRiuP8a87ybS0vFe1N6AU4KtDXFfxXoXSjAcVvN3iz0JrfKVqpo3@RWPoQ6YpNQazwwGXyxzH@KERHO00Q34w15a0k/Dws1pTDiyVeIdLNerNUXeJo6/e5vV/GbRVVflpHSfXJ1gn9vobmDJgf3RPX7Z0ZV1l8SxXa3m0@aHcc8Gx7xmCxFZcbDl79pW4imNpOc5bx9OTMN7Z4GsqvFXHThNIENhvrqOgMSeWwP0xVnVGRzQ/JZp6QJAV6NP6qENlgDIVeZviiYpNK/kBjYRaw2MLipQcelTf/DZU/akrZQ6g/eWM9tsIh0ylyFQzcNn7u4CPpuuwhSSctz3fSomLLNe7x8aacpNfyRcOV5F@LiW/h9BIS1x1b51xFc/iyhpTGUxIyskLH5y/jOXF8gxMh/UaAVfQ9m3ao0EoVp2bhbRjdh2W6pig33Bezn@SvG/8B)

Next answer must not exceed 416 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 2029 5835 2020 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh )X5  M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f  $*/main(){//\. /
00000050: 2b5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b53 6d69  +\.1+///\./*.Smi
00000060: 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d  V.ZZ;ooo"loG";?=
00000070: 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f22 3e3c 3e22 0a23  0%S!11ooo"><>".#
00000080: 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2222 0a23 6966 6465  define S"".#ifde
00000090: 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669  f __OBJC__.#defi
000000a0: 6e65 2053 222d 6576 6974 6365 6a62 4f22  ne S"-evitcejbO"
000000b0: 0a23 656e 6469 660a 7072 696e 7466 2822  .#endif.printf("
000000c0: 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374  C"S)/*/import st
000000d0: 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974  d.stdio;"D".writ
000000e0: 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a0a 3e22 4265 6675  e/**/;}/*.>"Befu
000000f0: 6e67 652d 3938 223b 352d 3b2c 2c2c 2c2c  nge-98";5-;,,,,,
00000100: 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 0a6e 715d 6a5c 6d37 2d3b  ,,,,,@.nq]j\m7-;
00000110: 6c28 655b 4b61 6764 2d2a 2f2f 2fe2 8e9a  l(e[Kagd-*///...
00000120: c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372 6168 43c2 a640  .....laocrahC..@
00000130: 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522  ,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

### Explanation

I compacted the Befunge code a bit, because why not. Then I had to fix Somme because of that. I need to add Somme-fixer to that TIO link...

Unefunge looks at the `v`, and reflects, since a `v` does not make sense in one dimension. You might think it will go to the end of the first line, but since the Fungespace has only one dimension, the entire code is treated as a single line. Therefore, `@,ka"89-egnufenU"` is executed.

Charcoal uses the `¿` conditional with an always true expression `⁵` to ignore the Unefunge code.

Answer (score 5):

## 13. Befunge-97, 358 bytes

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh )X5  M!M elif MOC SODeerF$*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
                  $$<  >1-v
>"Befunge-98";5-;00#^G#^_$>,,,,,,,,,,@
nq]j\m7-;l(e[Kagd)*///⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRnbUttI9hn9wrycGCaSwLZsCAQM9gSMSdghgYrJbDbgeGSpZSvo4tUF7MlkqvYH9gP2A/YP9nmr5lPmR7LndLdk@ZLM1O5Shenuc793m4EZjz5/Xodj2wYT2NBMh4F5AUmIu3HoTYdemEDC4gRGZhSwOIbBFF657PQn9uEuHCjr0A49zxzHDErt0GYlMAMbSsfRMPVZkMQliJmVuGEQgxNGMGBJwiJgkzGLXBZYTFEsM4EWWEireAFUYr7kH9WBA@twwpw0GLLKwY6ShKk1gnHkImMFRbsOTMMUTNI9E1gG37xjEKcRIyv80HadKaAG1fEU4hCSEcpLRmyKJAzcwPJSm9m4oEPw3OBOYdYohEoApY16CVUTtIXTbTq1w5hOlYvjV8/fHD/v9M9fnXbeNuvKyV@uO91maUN7sKBiHZEheklBG7gbwDODYWoOmaZ/VNY4z9I6bMxzqcJGvQwbnBP6G91fUtYu31xfvbkmxgOMGbLmmiDrtc7bq077unNKMMERFf85YvcERB/d4IGgLsGjJm4yghL0DsnsQFmTqnQwMFaC/shxyjDEDMjoCXHiJlBX1hxXWVswHuVrC6Zs1XXSQnCvwO2PktPtj@Ry7uBWFtFPFNNRkozjhmEM3WSUDqpW6BvX0fQ8uQwwNsxIoqmbhNmaMcM3Y8wo4yEyx5hTMXLIPAwlytsSlLhwvlZmMDS@ZPs2VKI04NlWBHZD38dULkUpZrsRjhMjphPxWY0GSwStoxaij6fJKAx2BIXjxiP@QYm3iN9GbI5lVRLLMgZuYODf1cq0sfKs0PRyErnPF6sE/OD6iH/v@nlF4bqa@GNoGTa7N4LU82C79bgOjx8DlaAEF3lcDj5Q7d6zCqk7JP0mEOaHluBbCYtnXASyrBoLh0XGeUnvZzYN8hPuC2cwcJdMmjWCBSpOgmuhz8@QmK5H9bG1c1CkP8N0Ob3sQvvyJTiuxwoBE8VcRH4eeitiOgw9HtY4srL1Kue/CYoGjqd8A5VKnNjNg31cpBLhyzY@XfLM04qfOK5BH8ghO8TlYI6XwovJAfU2OBpHrMUbUEtVMjuob1Antqj@wjELNJUwVL0aMdPW9Aan1yxqrmFka5beau5sU1MXu6P69lPaWRBgX3AD9aj1WGUe9n9Hfbz@USB9OlTLLLCbqorFnyl0ZHBVjgxS6za4Da542TdoqfIxIPuAJCjdBjdY@oDtRhT8o97N9fllj/BfsUmCkyZ@wGHipzidSBk2sRi1LmxCvHW26js734nlZn3HqNcaYrP1pKbroq9Widn6OrxgEzv1x7QrKZOJzZ35c4zc1Nh4bwD@GGrBtVyRRt6saERg6Rrr6zNHi7Hx@fN96NpgbI4uHr2tPIOr96Nffnn77FntFGqnpdFYHL4bgf52F@Dlo5fAPPT8y8s2dC9PGYvONjaxx7kBzgvDuFXA2LpV6lsGrY3Nb7q@@8M3794dhmFY8sLnpcPvmrVvu4/qdTqgBFbWbeag76BbwrXr4A76/cuTP7X7/QKswu7dxGIfBpeIhZFzHWmshq2qqxubhuuPwygBTOEq/rrhIXbQ6kPkJszY3DQOPxmbCiz9bGwcAbTqlXulVSz6w93KYa22/v75@vv@Rquc/zxTgr/2Ptz6TyuHnsZuvjeHtr6Jpv7293/8@u/f/vYvzwytyBy1f/3ns/KdWdo/qLBhkDoseFP67EShDz957gCEppuK1BinJdt7ojhNz/QHtglBg2d9UFajQZ71it0cqDRXbyeOQ7/qlqOpVX4LwUCq@tZAnQOJmpGn/ETEe/5M9BVVV6wmDjLM@zjGtqgdlE87ZxfHNF0rL4/f9v98cn7dpbP@y87L/kXnh85FuaaLCGhC/@pg7wnel1CqZlUzXpqtb1lVx0vjkaaXB@ozAw2yGcdCy@Ikcsea2lR1HW942PoqnotXo8n@Hvhu4PqmB8xPPTOhi9nCrQ5zkO5D@RXwIYzuYhixiJWpIB9cHB90Rl0EXegR@zL6OkKdhzBIh7Fggrh2yOJAFSwkB7q1jaNwYA68KQRUtHhVw5LGzEOK2c2Og0bMG6PAZCQxSEAycmMwB2ihya9VZTDjO/BZdo@zaFBjL4EQuxhmOP7xp7Jh4GEgGOAA9TyGSalkyRJPY4VnEr@vhaEXy3SCsRklrukpCtek0DhFHqF8cBrKGlo1jEwfmuBkqeUzP8Q21oSbV6hKb3Nvd3dnT57ebO/uNfB3C9XQJK3eQ1y5Vmzm5WslYkOXbjsxInxUz6/UBtQm9VqtDGr3vLBpv@WbWu3srKysqae0JdmEdzVbn55na0Q6LiCdFNcZwSfF8cyhEN0@w8MzE7s@YlwWN@@Km25xc5Vv8J5HbYhFURhpfjzUud8o151S5/Xry9cN@IjHn/BPbvGj6FNJV9YwPlW6gGp1XTAZsqRPYehTO9eIEy1QSenfnMEN@avX4xdijoLxJ7MaUg@VTZiVJpRcaSD6oi2ZYP2uLfCBrSbdgSOWpFHA@S2o80CDkNTxQlRmQUtlbeSuOpXsNIQeHcG@DlvghYryuvO8S@lDMRLRpeDxzxP@iUEVkRKJIELbI7oXxxdnRPsxi7AmmPA46GV8Xh1fIKgtQO15UPsiSx5NiJuBTgl0IkAn86ATAvE0k7Kuo1SKekFEVzNROaRNEJ7CUlIOOSXI6flMUA45eaHIRMJWGHr3rI9vvcjf516P/DIeD9HyOWB9j9xMbSl2gzgx8QGqESr2EaJCMqTI3HYT@T0e@LkzNuzlgZJSVmhBgpAhX6@K9Mlxt0MhvckiiPEqQ7Y7zXZXc7CrIiw7LeBmHCjLsQn2s5wV@ndvhDaGAfvwLez3uHq8VLJzHJPCBeIEkbizBFoTdriLhOmcITqoDEVJ@NDDNCA0mlrIqIZLum2SF7E1k9lERRjEeVZV5NelkkyDmCU5EjFwsf1H@KyQlQmmZeEcpAKVIreaC0wzXR6jMjiWHUdR1opG1XJdfNru8W1m5UI5Lxq7lpubU5AskRQELMipc7SswoWui3mhw2Op5JKkXJAZxwzHUcZ2@2tchdZf5Jp1rH0Nj/ph1EenUtYu1EcOQ/J07DFRKWxYhpE7HPESyzAQYJuJKTIeawAhunA3oRY9wNEw5fjIKtpXhH@bgTOoZD7r7VJuTwjh4CyJeHh4HjklmsSis1NCZbmTIPuPMyaN2vaED5miDsJJ8byTyhz0P7sq9OyveSrOAGXQuGXZTCA66Rq96LoCAccXmCL4HDXDXPYf6oG@cYc49Pa5sNl4FSz/UHpkbVSGaa4Q/6tI5aVfCNNyiHK7@KxdmRx83i5B0EN1qRCSSnXwnYsx@D@m0eI4lwk159c/klH5kFrl1kIAkbGI4LxfFsGz6hLeWYIXqnNlwqAtKyDcpwgdudJSmVQZe2ljtoUWCnnqNGYHlWYmVvovgxT5oZJfZ@isYvlFprPcn/GUiJJF5qw5dNTid/AzCgpo1P9gWf14hK8JzQpxkNHDRVB6q@4IfD56uYNoPfONS992SR4NWHE7RfSiaBcfevW9/k445heTOLLqmHNxsvqGRGCE5FaKNkCnuoBuL0Dn5g1ZFKce8eaMNunPdvEOjYIXMlZQICl/ZNzQC6NXlDFPq9P32IIkp3gnKAr0RfsnYSRuhkheJn0WDd/ndlOf5xhDudLhvVgjiS6b4hjf21mVNOaeBt0rroNwF@10qNCIzsu9iFherLiMfTiW18e5WVpgipouP2@IJQmnrvUleFacAmdZ8WX0bWV5GsqMwvcar70ACaJ0nHwhhwtwyt5tfuHK33FiLK1A4/cleoULtvta8TWhy9cE8Rc4RFM74N06TJNxStqoKr8w2XY0iwm@Lvhl8WHkeowzE9e3gD0gkjWKNC6MiHSOKOjFc09cFDkqct/AR8kAR8IdB0ipiIhwOhEvWnGcfRlanNZyqKhvAtfHqwJ9XcH/D5Vs1yH/bxFOFlrzmaIWOvoXiaUPkS7f5MQKD1wq/x3HH4XoaLsB4puxhpxKws/DfE05vFjiZSLdqTUK1SWOdn@f2/tV3NZR5Sc1lFSb7J7Rf/TQnAHzwgfiurc/4yqLb6VCeweNpXbHAU/3ZgwWW3Gx4eDoL3QTwdSyG7OMpydntrHE01B@rYibBhRuYLNrHRWdLqls9oepKjMqsnmZbOYJSZKjh@OvCpENRlfoZYYvKjYpZw80FqQ@i0wsXnrgUXnz/9ryR00hewj1J3esRWYwZBpFroyB28PPfXwk3RQ9JOmk5dlOWpRvucY9fr0pJumNfNFwJfnXYuJbOK2AxHXH1jlX0Ry@qiEl0ZSEjMzA9vjLeE4c3@CNkP6TgFX0PZt2qNAKFVdKg7sgfAiKdA1RbrjP736Sv6b/Bw)

Next answer must not exceed 465 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 2029 5835 2020 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh )X5  M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f  $*/main(){//\. /
00000050: 2b5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b53 6d69  +\.1+///\./*.Smi
00000060: 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d  V.ZZ;ooo"loG";?=
00000070: 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f22 3e3c 3e22 0a23  0%S!11ooo"><>".#
00000080: 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2222 0a23 6966 6465  define S"".#ifde
00000090: 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669  f __OBJC__.#defi
000000a0: 6e65 2053 222d 6576 6974 6365 6a62 4f22  ne S"-evitcejbO"
000000b0: 0a23 656e 6469 660a 7072 696e 7466 2822  .#endif.printf("
000000c0: 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374  C"S)/*/import st
000000d0: 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974  d.stdio;"D".writ
000000e0: 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a0a 2020 2020 2020  e/**/;}/*.      
000000f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2424 3c20              $$< 
00000100: 203e 312d 760a 3e22 4265 6675 6e67 652d   >1-v.>"Befunge-
00000110: 3938 223b 352d 3b30 3023 5e47 235e 5f24  98";5-;00#^G#^_$
00000120: 3e2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 0a6e 715d  >,,,,,,,,,,@.nq]
00000130: 6a5c 6d37 2d3b 6c28 655b 4b61 6764 292a  j\m7-;l(e[Kagd)*
00000140: 2f2f 2fe2 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372  ///........laocr
00000150: 6168 43c2 a640 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e  ahC..@,ka"89-egn
00000160: 7566 656e 5522                           ufenU"
```

### Explanation:

Uses `G` as a distinguishing thing between Befunge-97 and Befunge-98: in 97, it is `g` but relative to the current position, but in the Befunge-98 interpreter, it just reflects. As always, the Somme portion at the bottom had to be modified, but only by one character this time

Answer (score 5):

## 14. Befunge-96, 355 bytes

That's smaller than the previous answer!

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh )X5  M!M elif MOC SODeerF$*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
  >"8";    >    ]#;v
>#^Z"6"00G#^_$4->1+>,"Befunge-9",,,,,,,,,@
np#s)KhdpR>!}bbg$%*///⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRlZctvI9Vu4Qn7aoCwAIkiQlE1TlMixVlsZ2VJZ8sSxRHNAoEHCwlZYJHI8nqpcIAfIAXKDfKdqjjIXcd7rboDgYs9UEleZ6u63793kyEwmX75UyIFtE5PQsZmNA/OcpCHsotCbjb0wJSlNUjIx44AmCRnNyGuXHv9EP96FI6lCjkLPM6OEEvkotKlMzMAm8kE8znwapIlMEmqlbhgkxAljMqJpSmNCpxGNXRpYVJIsMyV9YgGt5AWklrAl@6iPHFIhh9TJgjGt7e5IaZhZExLFLjCWQLTrkFmYERN1zwXqxDfvKEmymKIVfmi7zoyABvVoRpKQpBOQl07oDEgocQPLy2xqwwIPiecGdxK1JiGpBUTebMqgGqctnbbw1A6TxdMdPE1C36c1x50iTIpm6SQMdpZOzw9ev3h78OJkePb6@ORdrykd/vX65Konb6oPFqlZ@2i6JktgNXMc8cxgnJljqmqfpA0mT66QzUUudbLZ1Mkm4wQRgoDJ0sbF2@vLt9fIeARRBtZMd2C9cfLu8uTo@uQYYZwjmPpzTO8RCF69gQNOLZNHPdjkBDIZ7KGjAmlDqHICobRS8GCBo5Mx5ExOL204rrSxZDOIVZcsqDY1FM6Z1sjtj4LB7Y8YGxaJfh76zxj8SZpGSdcwxm46yUZ1K/SN63h2ll4EEERqpPHMTcN8TanhmwmknvEQmxEkXwIccscSGRNcJjITztbSHAY2y7Zvk1qcBSwty8ArjCwgxBmUhRFGqcFizT/r8WiFoL/fB/Q8MRiF4yYT9oEZuox/BNgMy6qllmWM3MCAv@uVOYIStULTK0jEvlisE/CD6wP@vesXpQfreupHpG/Y9N4IMs8jrf5Wk2xtEaxVAS7zuBh9xCK/pzVUd4z6TUlYHFqcby0snzERwLJuLB2WGRe138ltGhUnzBfOaOSumDTvGEtUjATWXJ@fSWq6HpZFdWe3TH8K6XJ8cUWOLl4Rx/VoKWC86svIL0JvTUzHocfCmsRWvl7n/LdB2cBoxjakVktSu7fbgUUmEL5u47MVzzyr@anjGvgBHPLDr3No/w6H4rgteEisDB2i3Ab7UUz7rGP1laLdYaPBZm9h5YYRDVQFMRStHlPTVrUuo1ct7N9hbKuW1u/ttHBu8N1@s/UMdxYJoJG4gbLf31KoByPGUbYqnzjS5z1Fp4HdUxRoG7lC@wZTZd9AtW6D2@CSNYwuLhU2aUQHEQTybXADTYO4KeGt4tHg5vrsYoD4r@k0hWGWPMC88jMYgKgMnVoUex20L9Zr@82dne/4cru5YzQbXb6pPmloGm/EdWRWqZCXdGpnfoQ7WZpObebMnxPgpiTGB4PAP0MpuZYp0i3aHE4hKHqjUpk7mk@mL1/uQ9cmxvbk/NG72nNy@WHyyy/vnj9vHJPGsTyJ@OH7CdHePSXk1aNXhHrg@VcXR@Tq4pjS@HRzG7qjG8CAMYxbiRjVW6lZNXBtbP/pynd/@NP793thGMpe@ELe@67XeHz1qNnEA0x9qWJTB3xHrmRYuw7syHB4cfjno@GwBKvReze16MfRBWBB5FxHGKtCk7vSjG3D9aMwTgkkfx3@u@Ee9N76Q@ym1NjeNvY@G9sSIX25I@@hs/r4Majs3Uv9yof3cltuNF5UPgw3n9T6zWpfn@e3rOf/nktBVEm07yd29Kb/6PNoNN58vA12/vb3f/z679/@9i/PDK3YnBz9@s/n@p0pd3ZrdBxkDg3eyl@cOPTJT547IlzNbUmoC7OVtp9ITs8z/ZFtkqDLUj7QlXhUpLxk90YKTuHbqePgf6XqqEqd3XIgiopWHSlzEF8r9Y8hBMVRTzWsplOohBteSLrCIw8L3pBgUb5jKANNsnowEaEMkgT6q7qrH5@cnh/gdK69Ong3/Mvh2fUVng1fnbwanp/8cHKuNzQeEJVbVB@1n8ANDeSpVj3npdpa1ao7XpZMVE0fKc8NMNGmDAtsTdLYjVSlp2ga3Cmhh9Y8Fy5j006b@G7g@qZHqJ95ZopXwaV7JKQk3sCKS@dDGN8lZEJjqmN9Prgwh/AMmwo41UP2Ong/Bp3HZJSNE84EcO2QJoHCWQgOeE@M4nBkjrwZCbCG4XIIFQ6JCBTzuyQDTagXgcB0IjBQQDpxE2KOwEKTXct0YiZ3xKf5zdFC/0NrISE0NUh4@OPPRP@Aw4AzgEnseRTSUsrTJ5klEsstdt8LQy8RCUYiM05d05Mkpkmpj/LMAvnE6UobYNU4Nn3SI06ebD71Q@hqPXLzGlQZbLefPt1pi9Ob1tN2F/5XQQ1V0GoDwBVryaZesZZiOnbx2pQAwifl7FLpksa02WjoRLk6K22O3rFNo3F6qksbyjFuUTbiXc7Xx2f5GpAOSkiH5XVO8FlyPHPMRR@dwuGpCUMAMC7Km/flzVV5c1ls4MKIXYnGcRirfjLWmN8w1x355M2bizdd8gmOP8OfwuJH8WdZkzYgPnU6dVO1qXEmY5oOMQxD7O4qcsIFKCn8WzC4QX8NBuxCzVAg/mhWV@ih0Cm1shSTKwt4m7QFEwUEL/Eh1R5p4mmaxQHjt6TOA85FVMcLQZklLaWNibvuVLBTAbq/TzoaqRIvlKQ3Jy@uMH0wRjy6GDz2ecg@Iag8UjwReGgHSPfy4PwUaT/lEVY5ExYHTYcH3cE5gI446GgRdHSeJ4/Kxc1Bxwg65KDDRdAhgliaCVnXcSZEvUSiy7moAnKEEJbCQlIBOUbI8dlcUAE5fCmJRIJWGHr3dAivy9jvMK/Hvg7HY7B8Adhso5uxLSVukKQmPHlVRIU@glRABhS5225if8ACv3BGx4MiUELKGi1QEDBk63WRPjy4OsGQ3uQRhHjpJN8d57vLBdhlGZaflnBzDpjl0ASHec5y/a9uuDaGQTrkMekMmHqsVPJzGJzcBfwEkJizOFqP7DAXcdMZQ3CQTsqS4MUIaYBoOLWAUQOWOC7Ri9Ca0WykQgzkPK8q9OtKSWZBQtMCCRm40P5jeJ@IyiSmZcEcxAIVIqu9Jaa5LlugDIxxx5GkjbJRjUIXH7dtts2tXCrnZWM3CnMLCpTFkwKBJTlNhpZXONd1OS80siWUXJFUCDKThMI4ytm2vsWVa/1VrnnH6qhwNAzjITgVs3apPgoYkGeRR3ml0LFOJu54wkosxwCAbaYmz3ioAYBo3N2IWvYAQ4OUYyOrbF8Z/jgH51DBfN7bhdwBF8LAeRKx8LA8cmScxLyzY0LluZMC@09zJt1Ga8qGTFkH7qRk0Uk6A/3Prgo9@1ueSnKATlRmWT4TkE64Riu7rkTA8DkmDz5DzTFX/Qd6gG/cMQy9DhM2H6@c5R9Kj7yNijAtFOJ/Fami9EthWg1RYRebtWuTg83bFQh4qCkUAlKhDjx7IQb/xzRaHucioRb8@kcyqhhS69xaCiAw5hFc9MsyeF5d3Dsr8FJ1rk0YsGUNhPkUoBNXWCqSKmcvbMy38HBsTJ853flBrZeLFf7LIWV@oOS3GTrrWH6V6Tz35zwFomCRO2sBHbT4HfycAgMaDz9a1jCZwGtCtUIYZPhw4ZTeujsCm49e4SBcz33j4tdmgkeXrLmdAnpZtAsPvWZ7uBNG7GKSxFYTci5J19@QEAyQwkreBvBU49DWEnRh3qBFSeYhb8ZoG/@0yndoELyUsZwCSNkj4wZfGIOyjEVaDb8H5yQFxXtOUaIv2z8NY34zBHId9Vk2vMPsxj7PMMZipZEPfA0kmmiKEby38yrpLjwNri6ZDtxduNNIDUd0Ue5lRH254nL2YSSujwuztMQUNF193iBLFI5d62vwvDg5zqriq@gtaXUaioyC9xqrvQAI4ixKv5LDJThmb4tduIp3HB9La9DYfQlf4ZxtRy2/JjTxmkD@HAdpGrusW4dZGmWojaKwC5Ntx/OYwOuCXRYfJq5HGTN@fQvoAyBZk1hlwpBIY4icnj/3@EWRoQL3TXiUjGAk3DGAkAqIAMcT/qLlx/l3o@VpLYaK8jZwfbgq4NcV7JevtNUkxa9NMFlwzWaKUuroXyUWPgS6YlMQSyxwmfgBkD0KwdF2l/DvyrpiKnE/j4s15vByietIutPolqqLHz39fW4f1nGrgMpPGiCpMX16ir8hgjkj6oUPyLXdmXMVxbdWofZud6XdMcCz9pzBcisuNxwY/aVuwpladnee8fjkzDcWfxqKLxph0yWlG9j8WodFpwkqm/5hqtqcCm1eJZt7QpAU6GH0TSGiwWgSvszgRUWnev5Ao0Hm09iE4sUHHpY3@52YPWpK2YOoP7mRGpvBmKoYOR0C14bPDjySbsoeEnTC8nwnLCq2TOMBu96Uk/RGvGiYkuxrMf4tnFpCYrpD61yoaAZf15DSeIZCJmZge@xlvCCObeBGiD8sQBV9T2cnWGilipOz4C4IH4IyXZeXG@yLu5/gr2pflr8uLL4ptPjjO/@asJ5EHvRD5TaAUsVv/RB@U4N2XQGKJPP5156U/3zNfzNzxVeZFCINoxx/MpFSMwajgbF8kLjdTrXbbVW7T55t13x9T5aK3ijLPPq6tRh2Ts6uCD3@005tp8WzwENMlNsVV2awydPgfuJ2kxpD9m7cAcefd0Nsqcnj3afVnVb@jTb/nZazknWOqv0H) (added `somme-fix.py`: print what the first 18 characters of the bottom line should be changed to to make Somme work again)

Next answer must not exceed 461 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 2029 5835 2020 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh )X5  M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f  $*/main(){//\. /
00000050: 2b5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b53 6d69  +\.1+///\./*.Smi
00000060: 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d  V.ZZ;ooo"loG";?=
00000070: 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f22 3e3c 3e22 0a23  0%S!11ooo"><>".#
00000080: 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2222 0a23 6966 6465  define S"".#ifde
00000090: 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669  f __OBJC__.#defi
000000a0: 6e65 2053 222d 6576 6974 6365 6a62 4f22  ne S"-evitcejbO"
000000b0: 0a23 656e 6469 660a 7072 696e 7466 2822  .#endif.printf("
000000c0: 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374  C"S)/*/import st
000000d0: 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974  d.stdio;"D".writ
000000e0: 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a0a 2020 3e22 3822  e/**/;}/*.  >"8"
000000f0: 3b20 2020 203e 2020 2020 5d23 3b76 0a3e  ;    >    ]#;v.>
00000100: 235e 5a22 3622 3030 4723 5e5f 2434 2d3e  #^Z"6"00G#^_$4->
00000110: 312b 3e2c 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 222c  1+>,"Befunge-9",
00000120: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 400a 6e70 2373 294b  ,,,,,,,,@.np#s)K
00000130: 6864 7052 3e21 7d62 6267 2425 2a2f 2f2f  hdpR>!}bbg$%*///
00000140: e28e 9ac2 bfe2 81b5 6c61 6f63 7261 6843  ........laocrahC
00000150: c2a6 402c 6b61 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665  ..@,ka"89-egnufe
00000160: 6e55 22                                  nU"
```

### Explanation

I have redone the Befunge section because modifying someone else's Funge code is harder.

- `Z` is an undefined instruction in all versions. In -98, invalid instructions reflect, and all others ignore them.
- `G` (relative get) does not exist in -93.
- `]` (turn right) does not exist in -96.

Comment: Note: `G` also reflects in 98.

Answer (score 5):

## 15. brainfuck, 452 bytes

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh )X5  M!M elif MOC SODeerF$++[*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
  >"8";    >    ]#;v[
>#^Z"6"00G#^_$4->1+>,"Befunge-9",,,,,,,,,@
np#s)KhdpR>!}bbg$%*///]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[->+++++<]>[->+++++>+++++>++++++<<<]>+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRlZctvI9Vu4Qn7aoGwAIkCQkk3TlMixVlsZ2VJZ8sQxRXNAoEHCwlZYJGo8nqpcIAfIAXKDfKdqjjIXcd7rboDgYs9UEpUNdvdb@63dwNhKp1@@1Mi@4xCL0ImVT0LrjGQRzOLIv5/4UUYymmZkaiUhTVMyvievPXr0E/14E42lGjmMfN@KU0rkw8ihMrFCh8j7ySQPaJilMkmpnXlRmBI3SsiYZhlNCJ3FNPFoaFNJsq2M9IkNtJIfEiNlQ/ZojF1SIwfUzcMJNZ7tSFmU21MSJx4wlkC055L7KCcW6l4I1Elg3VCS5gnFXQSR47n3BDRoxPckjUg2BXnZlN4DCSVeaPu5Qx0Y4CLxvfBGovY0IkZI5M2WDKpx2srqNq46Ubq4uoOraRQE1HC9GcKk@D6bRuHO0urZ/usXb/dfHI9OXx8dv@u1pIO/Xh1f9uRN9c4mhr2HW9dkCXbNDEd8K5zk1oSq2idpg8mTa2RzkUuDbLZ0ssk4gYfAYbK0cf726uLtFTIeg5eBNdMdWG8cv7s4Prw6PkIY5whb/TmhtwgEqw5ggVPL5EEPJgWBTIa7aKhQ2hCqHIMr7QwsWOLoZAIxU9BLG64nbSztGcSqSzuotzQUzpka5PpHweD6R/QN80S/cP1ndP40y@K0a5oTL5vm44YdBeZVcn@anYfgRGpmyb2XRcWYUjOwUgg98y6xYgi@FDgUhiUyBrhMZCacjaU5DPYsO4FDjCQPWVhWgZfoWUBIckgLM4ozk/maPxvJeIWgv9cH9CIwGIXrpVP2wAhdxj8EbIZlG5ltm2MvNOF3vTKHkKJ2ZPkliZiXg3UCfvACwL/1gjL1YNzIgpj0TYfemmHu@2S7/6hFHj0imKsCXOVxPv6ISX5LDVR3gvrNSFQu2pyvEVXXmAhg2TCXFquMy9zvFHsalyvMFu547K1saV4xlqgYCYy5Pj@TzPJ8TIv6zrMq/QmEy9H5JTk8f0Vcz6cVh/GsryK/iPw1Pp1EPnNrmtjFeJ3x34bVDcb3bEIMI82c3rMODHKB8PU9Pl2xzFMjyFzPxAdwKBa/zqH9OxzK5fYKj3FieaGb2zcli2JhPhJEEstdlyjX4V6c0D4rc32lrJFYnbBD2JjuUUxDVUEMRWsk1HJUrcvoVRuLfpQ4qq31ezvb2Gz4bK@1/RRnNgmh@nihstd/pFAf@pKrPKp94kifdxWdhk5PUaDWFArtmUyVPRPVug6vwwtWZbo4VFh7EmVHEMjX4QAqDfEywuvLg@Hg6vR8iPiv6SyDDpjeQZMLcuiaqAyd2RQLJNQ8VqD7rZ2d7/hwq7VjtppdPqk/bmoar94NZFarkZd05uRBjDNZms0cZsyfU@CmpOYHk8CfqVRMyxTplrURWxdUCrNWmxuat7MvX24jzyHm1vTswTvjObn4MP3ll3fPnzePSPNInsZ88f2UaO@eEPLqwStCfbD8q/NDcnl@RGlyslmvD7agqnohNCbTvJaIWb@WWnUTx@bWny4D74c/vX@/G0WR7Ecv5N3ves2Hlw9aLVzAlJFqDnXBfORShrHnwoyMRucHfz4cjSowg956mU0/js8BC5znuWK/KhTHS83cMr0gjpKMQNI04L8X7ULNbtwlXkbNrS1z97O5JRHSlzvyLtqrj49hbfd2IPVrH97LbbnZfFH7MNp8bPRb9b4@TwxZL/6eS2FcS7Xvp078pv/g83g82Xy4BRsd/vb3f/z679/@9i/fiuzEmh7@@s86/A2MPv7U94b9Ylh91vf2AMKH9UbfgH@G0djbM/CvUS8AfNo3Cni98Vy/seTOM4NOwtyl4Vv5i5tEAfnJ98aEG2FLEsaAjk/bjyW351vB2LFI2GU5FepKMi5zSnJ6YwXPBtcz18X/St1VlQY7e0GYKFp9rMxBfKw0Pkbgclc90TBdTyDVBjxTdYWHFgx4mYRB9eSjDDXJ7kGfhjxLU6j66jP96PjkbB/PDMar/XejvxycXl3i2ujV8avR2fEPx2d6U@PuVvmOGuP2Yzg3gjzVbhS8VEer2w3Xz9Opqulj5bkJW3Qow4K9plnixarSUzQNTrpQ2Q3fgyPirNMmgRd6geUTGuS@leEBdel0CzGP58LyKHwXJTcpmdKE6lgA7jzojriGVQuM6iN7HayfgM4TMs4nKWcCuE5E01DhLAQHPL3GSTS2xv49CbFIwJEVSgiEOVDMT7gMNKV@DAKzqcBAAdnUS4k1hh1a7LCoEyu9IQEtzrM22h9qF4mgakI6wU9wLwoULIacAZwPfJ9CzEtF@KT3qcRii51Co8hPRYCR2Eoyz/IliWlSKdQ8skA@cbvSBuxqklgB6RG3CLaABhGUzR4ZvAZVhlvtJ0922mJ1sP2k3YX/dVBDFbTaEHDFWHKoX46lhE48PMylgPBJOb1QuqQ5azWbOlEuTyuTw3ds0myenOjShnKEU5SNeBfz8dFpMQak/QrSQXVcEHyWXN@acNGHJ7B4YkGXAYzz6uR9dXJZnVyUEzjGYs2jSRIlapBONGY3jHVXPn7z5vxNl3yC5c/wU@74QfJZ1qQN8E@DzrxMbWmcyYRmI3TDCNuHipxwAEoK@5YMBmiv4ZAd8xkK@B@31RV6KHRG7TzD4MpDXoQdwUQBwUt8SL1HWria5UnI@C2pc4eNF9XxI1BmSUtpY@qtWxXsVIDu7ZGORurEjyTpzfGLSwwf9BH3LjqPPQ/YE5zKPcUDgbt2iHQv989OkPZT4WGVM2F@0HS4Zu6fAeiQgw4XQYdnRfCoXNwcdISgAw46WAQdIIiFmZB1leRC1EskupiLKiGHCGEhLCSVkCOEHJ3OBZWQg5eSCCQohZF/S0dw502CDrN6EuiwPIGdLwBbbTQzlqXUC9PMgou4iqhQR5AKyICiMNsgCYbM8QtrdDIsHSWkrNECBQFDNl7n6YP9y2N06aDwIPhLJ8XsqJhdLMAuqrBitYJbcMAohyI4KmKW63854NqYJumQh6QzZOqxVCnWoXFyE/AVQGLG4mg9ssNMxLfOGIKBdFKVBPdYCANEw64FjJowxHaJVoTSjNtGKsRAzvOsQruupGQepjQrkZCBB@U/gVuTyExi2Tb0QUxQIbLeW2Ja6PIIlIE27rqStFHdVLPUJcBpm02LXS6l8/JmN8rtlhQoiwcFAityWgytyHCu63JcaOSRUHJFUinISlMK7ahgu/0trlzrr3ItKlZHhaVRlIzAqBi1S/lRwoA8j33KM4VOdDL1JlOWYgUGABwrs3jEQw4AROPmRtSqBRgahBxrWdX9VeEPC3ABFczntV3IHXIhDFwEEXMPiyNXxk7MKzsGVBE7GbD/NGfSbW7PWJOp6sCNlC4aSWeg/9lUke98y1JpAdCJynZW9ASkE6bRqqarEDB8jsmdz1ALzFX7gR5gG28CTa/DhM3bK2f5h8KjKKPCTQuJ@F95qkz9iptWXVTui/XatcHB@u0KBCzUEgoBqVAH7tXgg/9jGC23cxFQC3b9IxFVNql1Zq04EBhzDy7aZRk8zy5unRV4JTvXBgzsZQ2E2RSgU0/sVARVwV7ssZjCtbQ5e@p25wtGrxAr7FdAqvxAyW8zdNex/CrTeezPeQpEwaIw1gI6aPE7@AUFOjQZfbTtUTqF24RqR9DI8OLCKf11ZwTWH/3SQDie28bDl3mCR5esOZ0CelW0Bxe9Vnu0E8XsYJImdgtiLs3Wn5AQDJByl7wM4KrGodtL0IV@gztKcx95M0Zb@LNdPUOD4KWI5RRAyi4ZA7xhDKsyFmk1fDvPSUqK95yiQl/d/yxK@MkQyHXUZ3njHbZvrPMMYyJGGvnAx0CiiaIYw327yJLuwtXg8oLpwM2FM40Y2KLLdK8i6ssZV7CPYnF8XOilFaag6er1BlmicKxaX4MXyclxVhVfRd@WVruhiCi4r7HcC4EgyePsKzFcgWP0brMDV3mP421pDRo7L@EtnLPtqNXbhCZuE8if4yBN8xmr1lGexTlqoyjswOQ4ydwncLtgh8W7qedTxowf30J6B0j2NFGZMCTSGCKn59c9flBkqMB9Ey4lY2gJNwwgpAIiwHGF32j5cvHytdqtRVNR3oZeAEcFfF3Bvsdl2y1SfgODzoJj1lOUSkX/KrGwIdCVk5JYYo7LxWdJdikEQztdwt@VdUVX4naelGOM4eUU15F0p9mtZBdfevL73D6s41YDlR83QVJz9uQEv2zCdsbUj@6Qa7sz5yqSb61C7WfdlXLHAE/bcwbLpbhacKD1V6oJZ2o73XnE45WzmNj8aiheNMKkSyonsPmxDpNOE1QO/cNUxpwK97xKNreEICnRo/ibQkSB0SS8mcGNis704oJGwzygiQXJixc8TG/29ZpdairRg6g/ebGaWOGEqug5HRzXhmcHLkmDqoUEndh5MRM7KqdM4yE73lSDdCBuNExJ9lqMv4VTK0hMdyidCxnN4OsKUpbco5CpFTo@uxkviGMTOBHilwvIou/p/TEmWiXj5Dy8CaO7sErX5ekG8/LsJ/ir2pfl14Xlm0KbX76L14SNNPahHirXIaQqvvVD@MCAcl0DijQP@GtPyj@q8y95nniVScHT0Mrxm4yUWQlsGhjL@6nX7dS73e169/HTLSPQd2WprI2yzL2v24tu5@TsiNDj346MnW0eBT5iotyuODLDnnwNzideNzUYsj/whhx/Xg2xpKYPnz2p72wXb7T512POStY5qvYf)

Next answer must not exceed 587 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 2029 5835 2020 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh )X5  M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242b 2b5b 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b2f 2f5c  $++[*/main(){//\
00000050: 0a20 2f2b 5c0a 312b 2f2f 2f5c 0a2f 2a1b  . /+\.1+///\./*.
00000060: 536d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722  SmiV.ZZ;ooo"loG"
00000070: 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 223e 3c3e  ;?=0%S!11ooo"><>
00000080: 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 220a 2369  ".#define S"".#i
00000090: 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364  fdef __OBJC__.#d
000000a0: 6566 696e 6520 5322 2d65 7669 7463 656a  efine S"-evitcej
000000b0: 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966 0a70 7269 6e74  bO".#endif.print
000000c0: 6628 2243 2253 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274  f("C"S)/*/import
000000d0: 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77   std.stdio;"D".w
000000e0: 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 0a20 203e  rite/**/;}/*.  >
000000f0: 2238 223b 2020 2020 3e20 2020 205d 233b  "8";    >    ]#;
00000100: 765b 0a3e 235e 5a22 3622 3030 4723 5e5f  v[.>#^Z"6"00G#^_
00000110: 2434 2d3e 312b 3e2c 2242 6566 756e 6765  $4->1+>,"Befunge
00000120: 2d39 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 400a 6e70  -9",,,,,,,,,@.np
00000130: 2373 294b 6864 7052 3e21 7d62 6267 2425  #s)KhdpR>!}bbg$%
00000140: 2a2f 2f2f 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f  *///]........lao
00000150: 6372 6168 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3e 2b2b  crahC..++++[->++
00000160: 2b2b 2b3c 5d3e 5b2d 3e2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e2b  +++<]>[->+++++>+
00000170: 2b2b 2b2b 3e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 3c3c 5d3e  ++++>++++++<<<]>
00000180: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
00000190: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
000001a0: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
000001b0: 3c2b 2e40 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  <+.@,ka"89-egnuf
000001c0: 656e 5522                                enU"
```

### Explanation

```
++++[->+++++<]> 20
[->
+++++>
+++++>
++++++
<<<]> 100 100 120
+++++++.> 107 100 120: k
-.> 107 99 120: c
---.<< 107 99 117: u
-----. 102 99 117: f
++++++++. 110 99 117: n
-----.> 105 99 117: i
--.> 105 97 117: a
---.< 105 97 114: r
+. 105 98 114: b
```

Answer (score 5):

## 16. Trefunge-98, 472 bytes

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$+[*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,,
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@
noj6ZR42[jeeOCy(dm*///]]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[->+++++<]>[->+++++>+++++>++++++<<<]>+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRlZctvI9Vu4Qn7akGwAIkCQlE3TlMjRbiuRLZUlzzimaA4INEhYWFhYJNIeT1UukAPkALlBvlM1R5mLOO91N0BwsT2VhCWR3f2Wfv32BoZWMv7yZZMcOA6xCB1Z2Si0zkkawWwS@bORH6UkpUlKxlYc0iQhwxl55dHjj/TDbTSUNslR5PvWJKFEPoocKhMrdIh8EI@ygIZpIpOE2qkXhQlxo5gMaZrSmNDphMYeDW0qSbaVki6xgVbyQ2IkbMi@qkOXbJJD6mbhiBrPdqQ0yuwxmcQeMJZga88lsygjFsqeb6iTwLqlJMliiqcIIsdzZwQkqE5mJIlIOob90jGdAQklXmj7mUMdGOAi8b3wVqL2OCJGSOStugyicdrSagNXnShZXN3B1SQKAmq43hRh0mSWjqNwZ2n1/ODV8zcHz08GZ6@OT9526tLhX69PrjrylnpvE8Pew6NrsgSnZoojvhWOMmtEVe2TtMH2kzfJ1iKXKtmq62SLcQILgcFkaWMItgWGTOJulKWTLBUMxOF@ieldF21hp9TJeS@vG6EvbYCmHxA7mBDOhuRA8ujRegBQ7aJGQ2mD8/0pjsKRwKqSF3TqZMGkDdDp1CG5cK4nbSypB9SiLh22UtdAP0Jcg9z8vKWiE3Em2s3PaExmum7uK5/RW8ZpOknapjny0nE2rNpRYF7Hs7P0IgSrUzONZ14a5WNKzcBKwFfN@9iagLcmwCG3BJExImQiMxHYWJrDjgHgBA4x4ixkflwGXqErAEKcQRyZ0SQ1mXPw72o8XCHo7nUBPfckRuF6yZh9oUsv4x8BNsOyjdS2zaEXmvC7XpgjiGk7svyCRMyLwboNfvQCwL/zgiJWYVxNwQW6pkPvzDDzfdLoPqqjb6BdBLjM42L4AbPCHTVQ3BHKNyVRsWhzvkZUXmNbAMuqubRYZlwki1Z@pmGxwnThDofeypHmKWaJipHAmMvzC0ktz8eIquw8K9OfgrscX1yRo4uXxPV8WjIYTxNl5OeRv8amo8hnZk1iOx@vU/6bsHzAyYxNiGEkqdN51oJBJhC@fsanK5p5agSp65n4BRzyxa9zaH6HQ7HcXOExjC0vdDP7tmCRL8xHK0TX8XcOncYLh5ZY1LtEuQn3JjHtsozaVYp0jCkRi5GNiSKa0FBVEEPRqjG1HFVrM3rVxvoSxY5qa93OTgPrGp/t1RtPcWaTEIqjFyp73UcK9aEEusqjzU8c6fOuotPQ6SgK5KpcoD2TibJnolg34U14yfJTG4cKq4QiYQkC@SbsQY4iHmQ3lpke9HvXZxd9xH9FpykU2@Qe6mmQQYFGYejUppCVMWeyWtCt7@z8wIfb9R2zXmvzSeVxTdN4oagis83NPCXjTJYwKaOovyTATUnM9yaBj6mUVMsEaRdZFask5Bhzc3OuaF45v3y5izyHmNvj8wdvjX1y@X78669v9/drx6R2LI8nfPHdmFTePiHyywcvCfVB8y8vjsjVxTGl8elWpbcN6dgLoQSa5o1EzMqNVK@YODa3/3QVeD/@6d273SiKZD96Lu/@0Kk9vHpQr@MCxpq06VAXtEeuZBh7LszIYHBx@OejwaAEM@idl9r0w/ACsMB2niuOq0JWvdLMbdMLJlGcEnC8Kvx70S4k@@p97KXU3N42dz@b2xKk9mt5d/PjQD6U9f1uo7JLoC@AT79H7nY3d1u3@tNZw9jd13WpW46pzffvarXnm@8HW4@Nbr3S1YvPvhRGH5rvXj9u9D5QenE0U51gGw7f7//@93/89u/f//Yv34rs2Bof/fbPCnx6Rhd/Knv9bj4sf1f29gDCh5Vq14A/w6ju7Rn4qVZyAJ92jRxeqe7rt5bcembQUZi5NHwjf3HjKCAffW9IuGa2JaEhaD1o87HkdnwrGDoWCdsszkJdiYdFnElOZ6hgk3IzdV38VyquqlRZ6weuo2iVoTIH8bFS/RCBH7jqqYYhfArh1@PRqyvc3WDAky4Myo2X0tckuwNVH2IvSaCGqM/045PT84Prk2PdeHnwdvDT4dn1Fa4NXp68HJyf/Hhyrtc07gMqP1F12HwMbSvsp9rVnJfqaBW76vpZMlY1fajsm3BEhzIsOGuSxt5EVTqKpkGjDXXC8D3oUKetJgm80Assn9Ag860U@@Ol5hriANvSohO/j@LbhIxpTHVMCvce1Fpcw0wGSvWRvQ7aj0HmERlmo4QzAVwnokmocBaCAzbPkzgaWkN/RkJMHNAxQ1oB3weKeYPNQGPqT2DDdCwwcIN07CXEGsIJLdar6sRKbklA83baRv1DPiMRZFKIMfgJZiJpwWLIGUC34fsUwkDK3SeZJRLzLdYER5GfCAcjEytOPcuXJCZJKXlzz4L9iQtdJZxqFFsB6RA3d7aABhGk0g7pvQJR@tvNJ092mmK113jSbMN/BcRQBa3WB1wxlhzqF2MppiMPW8MEED4pZ5dKm9Sm9VpNJ8rVWWly9JZNarXTU13aUI5xinsj3uV8fHyWjwHpoIR0WB7nBJ8l17dGfOujU1g8taDyAMZFefKuPLkqTy6LCTTFmAhpHEexGiQjjekNfd2VT16/vnjdJp9g@TP8FCd@EH@WNWkD7FOlUy9V6xpnMqLpAM0wwJKiIiccgJBCvwWDHuqr32c3CoYC9sdjtYUcCp1SO0vRubKQZ2ZHMFFg4yU@pNIhdVxNszhk/JbEucdijOL4EQizJKW0MfbWrQp2KkD39khLIxXiR5L0@uT5FboP2ohbF43Hvg/ZNxiVW4o7AjdtH@leHJyfIu2n3MIqZ8LsoOlwyz04B9ARBx0tgo7Oc@dR@XZz0DGCDjnocBF0iCDmZmKv6zgTW71Aosv5VgXkCCHMhcVOBeQYIcdn840KyOELSTgSpMLIv6MDuHLHQYtpPQ50WB7ByReA9SaqGdNS4oVJaoU2VREV8ghSARlQ5GrrxUGfGX5hjY76haHELmukwI2AIRuvs/ThwdUJmrSXWxDspZN8dpzPLhdgl2VYvlrCzTmgl0MSHOQ@y@W/6nFpTJO0yEPS6jPxWKjk61A4uQr4CiAxZXG0DtlhKuJHZwxBQTop7wR3Y3ADRMOqBYxqMMRyiVqE1IzHRirEQM7zqEK9roRkFiY0LZCQgQfpP4Y7mIhMYtk21EEMULFlpbPENJflEQgDZdx1JWmjfKhaIUuA0yab5qdcCuflw24Uxy0ocC/uFAgs7VNnaHmEc1mX/UIjj4SQKzsVG1lJQqEc5Wwb3@LKpf4q1zxjtVRYGkTxAJSKXrsUHwUMyLOJT3mk0JFOxt5ozEIsxwCAY6UW93iIAYBoXN2IWtYAQwOXYyWrfL4y/GEOzqGC@Ty3i337fBMGzp2ImYf5kStjJeaZHR0q950U2H@aM2nXGlNWZMoycCUli0rSGeh/VlXkO9/SVJIDdKKyk@U1AemEarSy6koEDJ9jcuMz1BxzVX8gB@jGG0HRa7HN5uWVs/xD7pGnUWGmhUD8ryxVhH7JTKsmKs7Fau1a52D1dgUCGqoLgYBUiAN3bbDB/9GNlsu5cKgFvf4RjyqK1Dq1lgwIjLkFF/WyDJ5HF9fOCrwUnWsdBs6yBsJ0CtCxJ04qnCpnL86YT@GKWps@ddvzBaOTbyv0l0PK/EDIbzN017H8KtO57895CkTBIlfWAjpI8R38nAINGg8@2PYgGcNtQrUjKGR4ceGU/roegdVHv1AQjue68fDRoODRJmu6U0Avb@3BRa/eHOxEE9aYJLFdB59L0vUdEoIBUpySpwFc1Ti0sQRdqDd4oiTzkTdjtI0/jXIPDRsveSynAFJ2yejhDaNf3mORViMPmNxAUlC84xQl@vL5p1HMO0Mg11Ge5YO32LkxzzOMkRhp5D0fA4kmkuIE7tt5lLQXrgZXl0wGri6cacTAEl2EexlRX464nH00Ee3jQi0tMQVJV683yBI3x6z1NXgenBxnVfBV9Ia0Wg2FR8F9jcVeCARxNkm/4sMlOHpvgzVcxT2Ol6U1aKxfwls4Z9tSy7cJTdwmkD/HQZraM5atxQuhDlEU1jA5Tjy3CdwuWLN4P/Z8ypjx9i2k94Bkj2OVbYZEGkPk9Py6xxtFhgrct@BSMoSScMsAYldABDiu8BstX84fyJartSgqypvQC6BVwMcV7HVg2qiT4hUcVBYcs5qilDL6V4mFDoGumBTEEjNcJt6KskshKNppE/6srC2qEtfzqBijDy@HuI6kO7V2Kbr40pPvc3u/jtsmiPy4BjvVpk9O8cUqHGdI/egeuTZbc64i@NYK1HzWXkl3DPC0OWewnIrLCQdKfymbcKa20557PF4584nNr4biQSNM2qTUgc3bOgw6TVA59A9TGXMqPPMq2VwTgqRAjybf3EQkGE3CmxncqOhUzy9oNMwCGlsQvHjBw/BmL8/ZpabkPYj60ZuosRWOqIqW08FwTfhuwSWpV9aQoBMnz2fiRMWUSdxn7U3ZSXviRsOEZI/F@FM4tYTEZIfUuRDRDL4uIaXxDDcZW6Hjs5vxwnZsAh0hvs2AKPoLnZ1goJUiTs7C2zC6D8t0bR5uMC96P8Ff1b4sPy4snhTa/PKdPyasJhMf8qFyE0Ko4lM/hPcMSNebQJFkAX/sSfk7ff5e0BOPMilYGko5vqeRUiuGQwNj@SDx2q1Ku92otB8/3TYCfVeWitwoy9z6ur1odk7OWoQOf59k7DS4F/iIifu2RcsMZ/I16E@8dmIwZL/n9Tn@PBtiSk0ePntS2WnkT7T5u2jOStbF2/P/AA)

Next answer must not exceed 613 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835 2022 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh +X5 "M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242b 5b2a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a  $+[*/main(){//\.
00000050: 202f 2b5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b53   /+\.1+///\./*.S
00000060: 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b  miV.ZZ;ooo"loG";
00000070: 3f3d 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f22 3e3c 3e22  ?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
00000080: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2222 0a23 6966  .#define S"".#if
00000090: 6465 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43 5f5f 0a23 6465  def __OBJC__.#de
000000a0: 6669 6e65 2053 222d 6576 6974 6365 6a62  fine S"-evitcejb
000000b0: 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a 7072 696e 7466  O".#endif.printf
000000c0: 2822 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69 6d70 6f72 7420  ("C"S)/*/import 
000000d0: 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772  std.stdio;"D".wr
000000e0: 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a0a 2022 7254  ite/**/;}/*. "rT
000000f0: 223b 237a 5f22 4222 2c40 3e32 2b3b 2020  ";#z_"B",@>2+;  
00000100: 3e20 2020 205d 5b20 763b 233b 386b 2c37  >    ][ v;#;8k,7
00000110: 7932 2d3b 402c 2c0a 3e22 4265 6675 6e67  y2-;@,,.>"Befung
00000120: 652d 3936 2223 5e5a 3030 4723 5e5f 2434  e-96"#^Z00G#^_$4
00000130: 2d3e 312b 3e2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  ->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@
00000140: 0a6e 6f6a 365a 5234 325b 6a65 654f 4379  .noj6ZR42[jeeOCy
00000150: 2864 6d2a 2f2f 2f5d 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281  (dm*///]].......
00000160: b56c 616f 6372 6168 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b  .laocrahC..++++[
00000170: 2d3e 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 5d3e 5b2d 3e2b 2b2b  ->+++++<]>[->+++
00000180: 2b2b 3e2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c  ++>+++++>++++++<
00000190: 3c3c 5d3e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e  <<]>+++++++.>-.>
000001a0: 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b  ---.<<-----.++++
000001b0: 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e  ++++.-----.>--.>
000001c0: 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e40 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65  ---.<+.@,ka"89-e
000001d0: 676e 7566 656e 5522                      gnufenU"
```

### Explanation

If Funge-98 is detected, the number of dimensions is queried using `7y`. Additionally, I changed the DOS code a little to remove the `)`, making it possible to use Brain-Flak. The `)` has been changed into a `+`, so a different `+` was removed (after `$` from DOS). Also, Somme has a `[` in it now, so brainfuck code got another `]`.

Comment: And the `++` -> `+` as well, since you have a plus in the DOS code

Comment: @Zacharý done. Is it clear?

Answer (score 5):

## 19. Haskell, 690 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*/main(){//\
 /+ #\
 echo hsab<<'EOF' #>>
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@
n*'um{Z'; 5kziZ<m%*///><>}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";main=putStr"lleksaH"-- *///@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTpZcttIlt/CFfonDcoGIAIESdmyTJFsa7XdY1sKy1XtMUWzQSBBwsLCwCJRVqkj5gJ9gD7A3GC@J6KP0hfxvJcLCC6uqphu2SIz86351kxAYyebfv9eI4eeRxxCJ04xiZ23JE9gNkvCu0mY5CSnWU6mThrTLCPjO/I@oCff6NfrZKzUyHEShs4so0Q9TjyqEif2iHqYToqIxnmmkoy6eZDEGfGTlIxpntOU0PmMpgGNXaoorpOTPnGBVgljYmVsyD4aY5/UyBH1i3hCrRe7Sp4U7pTM0gAYKyA68MldUhAHdZcCTRI515RkRUpxF1HiBf4dAQ0aszuSJSSfgrx8Su@AhJIgdsPCox4McJGEQXytUHeaECsm6nZLBdU4bWW1jateki2v7uJqlkQRtfxgjjBldpdPk3h3ZfXt4ftXPx2@Oh29eX9y@qnXUo7@8@PpZU/d1m9dYrld3LqhKrBrZjgSOvGkcCZUN@6VLSZPrZHtZS4Nst0yyTbjBB4Ch6nK1hh8CwyZxv2kyGdFLhiIzf2S0ps@@sLNqSd5r65bcahsgaUfETeaEc6GSCB58mQzAKgO0KKxssX5/jlN4onAapDXdO4V0awD0PncI1I5P1C2VswDZtFXNltvGWAfoa5Frv6yrWMQcSbG1V/Qmcx1fRkrDxgt0zyfZR3bngT5tBg33CSyP6Z3b/LzGLxO7Ty9C/JEjim1IyeDWLVvU2cG0ZoBB@kJomJGqERlKrCxsoCdAMCLPGKlRcziuAq8xFAAhLSAPLKTWW6z4OCfjXS8RtDv9gFdRhKj8INsyj4wpFfxjwGbYblW7rr2OIht@N6szDHktJs4YUki5uVgk4Cfgwjwb4KozFUYN3IIgb7t0Rs7LsKQtPtPWhgb6BcBrvI4H3/FqnBDLVR3gvrNSVIuupyvlVTXmAhg2bBXFquMy2KxL/c0LleYLfzxOFjb0qLErFAxEhhzfX4huROEmFH13RdV@jMIl5PzS3J8/o74QUgrDuNloor8Kgk3@HSShMytWerK8Sbj/xRXNzi7YxNiWVnu9V7sw6AQCD/e4/M1yzy3otwPbPwADnLxxxz2foNDuby3xmOcOkHsF@51yUIuLEZrRB/T39h0nv5g04yn5YfOsrypA/KOcPTaEfKIdbhECKVT5V9rTF872TUNQ5bEwIpNBJLC6o1PtKu4O0tpn9XyvlY2AizG2AZdLFHJjMa6hhia0Uip4@lGh9HrLna2JPV01@j3dtvYUfms22o/x5lLYmjLQax1@080GkLz9bUntXuO9HCgmTT2epoGVVIq1LWZKl0b1bqKr@ILVhk7ONRYDxalUhCoV/EAqiMJoK6ymvhoOPj45nyI@O/pPIc2n91CJ48KOBqgMnTuUugHWK1ZF@q3dnf/yIc7rV271ezwSf1p0zB4i2ogs1pNNgOcqQq2A1T1lwy4aZn9xSbwY2sV0zJFOmU9x/4MnrBrtYWhec/@/v0mCTxi71j3lkVq0w@PPlkvycWX6V//@unly@YJaZ6o0xu@@HlK6p@eEfXdo3eEhmD/d@fH5PL8hNL0bPuhDj@DHWgJQQxt2LavFGLXSQ2@WAuYZs6429VOz880Uuv3lVbdRhx75w@TifsqCn7@w@fPB0mSqGHySj34Y6/5@PJRqwULXVbflZpHfbAxuVRhHPgwI6PR@dGfjkejCsyiN0Hu0q/jc8ACDwe@MIoOVf/SsHfsIJolaU4gMRrwGyQH0Iwat2mQU3tnxz54sHe6XQXi9qN6UPs2Uo9U82W/XT8gcHKBn@GA3BzUDvavzed3bevgpWmSLuD3q5lf@/K52XxV@zLafmr1W/W@Wf68VOIdrYjuP2sH5Nn1t@BzN3q8A2aADT4M//m3v//jf//5X/8TOombOtPjf/w3s6jVxa96f9iVw3q38tnvA6QrAPVG34L/ltXodi38adQlgE/7loQDar@vL34M/GfcP5T/@UxCSthA1wfDwVDiDA2YciD7BiiCAcDWGWtcAArAYViIawjse2I9jHqqoR5g2PTgbHKZp2oY0uvMea1CQKJ1XprXjrr/wqKTuPBp/JP63U@TiHwLgzHh3txRhFehGNG9p4rfC51o7Dkk7rAKEptaOi4riOL1xhqWrau57@OvVvd1rcGO05AUmlEfawsQH2uNrwnEta@fGViczqCwDHhdMjWeSDDgjQwG1cOsNjQUtwcnKagqWQZ9WX9hnpyevT38eHpiWu8OP43@fPTm4yWujd6dvhu9Pf359K3ZNHjc6nxHjfHeU7gKgDzdbUheumfU3YYfFtlUN8yx9tKGLXqUYcFeszwNZrrW0wwDLi/Qe60wgFP/fH@PREEcRE5IaFSETo53jpULC@Q2HvXL281tkl5nZEpTamK5uw2gnOMa1mgwaojsTbB@CjpPyLiYZJwJ4HoJzWKNsxAc8EIyS5OxMw7vSIwlEW4hUDAhX4FicWlhoCkNZyAwnwoMFJBPg4w4Y9ihw87/JoEWQyIqrygu2h8qNUmgR0BdgK/oTpRjWIw5AzjBQaRB0ioyfLK7TGGxxS4WSRJmIsDIzEnzwAkVhWlSaUs8skA@8eGkDruapE5EesSXwRbRKIEm0SOD96DKcGfv2bPdPbE6aD/b68BvHdTQBa0xBFwxVjwalmMlpZMAj9sZINxrby60DmnOW82mSbTLN5XJ8Sc2aTbPzkxlSzvBKcpGvIvF@OSNHAPSoaRhHI4qJEeS5EGBQ8KECz8@g8UzB7oqYJxXJ5@rk8vq5KKcwFUDyzdN0yTVo2xiMMthtPvq6YcP5x865B6WH@Cr3POj9EE1lC3wUIPOg1xvGZzJhOYjdMQI26WOnHAASgoLlwwGaLHhkN3TGApEAG6rI/TQ6Jy6RY7hVcS8n3iCiQaCV/iQeo@0cDUv0pjxW1HnFg8aqE6YgDIrWipb02DTqmCnA7TbJfsGqZMwUZQPp68uMYDQS9y/6D72ecQ@wa3cUzwUuHOHSPf68O0Z0t5LH@ucCfODYZIaOXwLoGMOOl4GHb@V4aNzcQvQCYKOOOhoGXSEIBZoQtbHtBCiXiPRxUJUCTlGCAtiIamEnCDk5M1CUAk5eq2IQIJimIQ3dBQlXhrtM6unkQnLE9j5ErC1h2bGwpQFcZY7sUt1RIVKglRABhTSbIM0GjLHL63RybB0lJCyQQsUBAzZeJOnjw4vT9GlA@lB8JdJ5OxEzi6WYBdVmFyt4EoOGOVQBkcyZrn@lwOujW2TffKY7A@ZeixV5Dq0Tm4CvgJIzFgcrUd2mYn41hlDMJBJqpKULTxpIxr2LWDUhCE2TLQiFGfcNlIhBnJeZBXadS0lizijeYmEDAJoACncbEVmEsd1oRNiggqR9d4KU6nLE1AGGrnvK8pWdVPNUpcIp3tsKne5ks6rm90qt1tSoCweFAisyGkxNJnhXNfVuDDIE6HkmqRSkJNlFBqSZNv@Na5c6x9ylRVrX4elUZKOwKgYtSv5UcKAvJiFlGcKnZhkGkymLMUkBgA8J3d4xEMOAMTg5kbUqgUYGoQca1rV/VXhjyVYQgXzRW0XcodcCAPLIGLuYXHkq9iLeWXHgJKxkwP7@wWTTrM9Z02mqgM3UrZsJJOB/mVTJaH3a5bKJMAkOtuZ7AlIJ0xjVE1XIWD4HJM7n6FKzHX7gR5gm2ACTW@fCVu0V87yd4WHLKPCTUuJ@P/yVJn6FTetu6jcF@u1G4OD9ds1CFioJRQCUqEOgXIF6P@@MFpt5yKgluz6eyKqbFKbzFpxIDDmHly2yyp4kV3cOmvwSnZuDBjYywYIsylAp4HYqQgqyV7sUU7hWt2cP/c7iwWrJ8UK@0lIlR8o@esM/U0sf8h0EfsLngJRsJDGWkIHLX4DX1KgQ9PRV9cdZVO4T@huAo0Mry6cMtx0RmD9MSwNhOOFbQJ84Cp4dMiG0ymgV0UHcNVr7Y12kxk7mGSp24KYy/LNJyQEA6TcJS8DuGpwaHsFutRvcEdZESJvxmgHv9rVMzQIXolYTgGk7JIxwBvGsCpjmdYgj5jeQFJSfOYUFfrq/udJyk@GQG6iPqsb32f7xjrPMCZiZJAvfAwkhiiKM7hxyyzpLF0NLi@YDtxcODOIhS26TPcqormacZJ9MhPHx6VeWmEKmq5fb5AlCseq9SO4TE6Os674OnpbWe@GIqLgvsZyLwaCtJjlP4jhChyjt80OXOU9jrelDWjsvIT3cM52X6/eJgxxm0D@HAdpmi9YtRav2XpE09iByfPShU/gdsEOi7fTIKSMGT@@xfQWkNxpqjNhSGQwRE7Pr3v8oMhQgfs2XErG0BKuGUBIBUSA4wq/0fJl@bC52q1FU9F@ioMIjgr4wIK9ZM3bLVK@2ITOgmPWU7RKRf8hsbAh0JWTklhhjivEu2Z2KQRDex3Cn5Z1RFfidp6UY4zh1RQ3kXS32alkF1969tvcvmziVgOVnzZBUnP@7AxfV8N2xjRMbpHr3v6Cq0i@jQrtveislTsGeL63YLBaiqsFB1p/pZpwpq7XWUQ8XjnlxOVXQ/GoESYdUjmBLY51mHSGoPLo76ayFlS453WyhSUESYmezH5ViCgwhoI3M7hR0bkpL2g0LiKaOpC8eMHD9GZ/ksAuNZXoQdRvwUxPnXhCdfScCY7bg899uCQNqhYSdGLnciZ2VE6ZxkN2vKkG6UDcaJiS7MEYfw6nV5CY7lA6lzKawTcVpDy9QyFTJ/ZCdjNeEscmcCLENzWQRf9B704x0SoZpxbxdZzcxlW6Dk83mJdnP8FfN76vPjAsnxW6/PItHxQ2slkI9VC7iiFV8bkfwgcWlOsaUGRFxB98Uv6XEvyFXCAeZlLwNLRyfAel5E4KmwbG6mEWdPbrnU673nn6fMeKzANVKWujqnLvm@6y2zk5OyL0@Lsya7fNoyBETJTbEUdm2FNowPkk6GQWQw4HwZDjL6ohltTs8Ytn9d22fKbN3/BzVqop/ibh/wA)

Next answer must not exceed 897 bytes.

### Explanation

After working for a long time on how to integrate Haskell with the FreeDOS COM binary code and finding an ugly solution, it didn't work with the interpreter on TIO and thus I pinged @NieDzejkob which quickly found another way, thanks!

Instead of `/* multi-line comment */` Haskell uses `{- multi-line comment -}`, so `void /* ...` will get properly parsed. The way this polyglot handles it, is to use `void` as an identifier for defining the operator `(/*-)` after which follows a long comment, a new identifier `_` and a definition and finally the `main`-function.

Basically I only needed to take care of Unefunge-98 (just moving it to the end of the file, fixing Somme and rebalancing & no-opping the newly integrated parentheses for Brain-Flak. This worked nicely because I had a useless definition floating around, where I could just put the only tricky paren `)`.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f6d  ODeerF$}++++[*/m
00000050: 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f 2b20 235c  ain(){//\. /+ #\
00000060: 0a20 6563 686f 2068 7361 623c 3c27 454f  . echo hsab<<'EO
00000070: 4627 2023 3e3e 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a  F' #>>.1+///\./*
00000080: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
00000090: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
000000a0: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
000000b0: 2222 0a23 6966 6465 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43  "".#ifdef __OBJC
000000c0: 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 222d 6576  __.#define S"-ev
000000d0: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
000000e0: 7072 696e 7466 2822 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69  printf("C"S)/*/i
000000f0: 6d70 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b  mport std.stdio;
00000100: 2244 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f  "D".write/**/;}/
00000110: 2a3c 3c0a 2022 7254 223b 237a 5f22 4222  *<<. "rT";#z_"B"
00000120: 2c40 3e32 2b3b 2020 3e20 2020 205d 5b20  ,@>2+;  >    ][ 
00000130: 763b 233b 386b 2c37 7932 2d3b 402c 2c20  v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, 
00000140: 3c3c 3c0a 3e22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936  <<<.>"Befunge-96
00000150: 2223 5e5a 3030 4723 5e5f 2434 2d3e 312b  "#^Z00G#^_$4->1+
00000160: 3e2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 0a6e 2a27  >,,,,,,,,,,@.n*'
00000170: 756d 7b5a 273b 2035 6b7a 695a 3c6d 252a  um{Z'; 5kziZ<m%*
00000180: 2f2f 2f3e 3c3e 7d5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2 81b5  ///><>}]........
00000190: 6c61 6f63 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d  laocrahC..++++[-
000001a0: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  <+++++>]<[-<++++
000001b0: 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e  ++<+++++<+++++>>
000001c0: 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e  >]<<<+++++++.>-.
000001d0: 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b  >---.<<-----.+++
000001e0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e  +++++.-----.>--.
000001f0: 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828  >---.<+.>>>(((((
00000200: 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b  (((((()()()){}){
00000210: 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828  }){}){}()){})(((
00000220: 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28  )()()()){}){})[(
00000230: 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928  ([][]){}){}()])(
00000240: 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b  []()){})[]())(([
00000250: 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828  [][]()]([]()((((
00000260: 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d  ([][][])){}{})[]
00000270: 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d  ){})))[]())({ -}
00000280: 5f3d 2229 223b 6d61 696e 3d70 7574 5374  _=")";main=putSt
00000290: 7222 6c6c 656b 7361 4822 2d2d 202a 2f2f  r"lleksaH"-- *//
000002a0: 2f40 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e  /@,ka"89-egnufen
000002b0: 5522                                     U"
```

Answer (score 5):

## 30. 99, 1187 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#,,,,"79-egnuferdauQ"_v#!$G0001<>
      @,,,,,,,,,,,"79-egnuferT"<>
.l           .   .*///{}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//TJri$8Al|?lz=a20-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLcttIkmfhF@ZSAtUGIBIEKdmyRJFsi3rY7rEtjaXu8ZqiOSBQJGHhwcFDoiyrI@YHpiP2tLGHndjLRuzG7GUj9rwR8yn@gvkDb2Y9QPBhd8fM0BZZVfmszKzMLJADOxl//lwiB65LbEJHdjYK7RckjWA2ifzbkR@lJKVJSsZ2HNIkIYNb8sqjRx/o@6tooJTIYeT79iShRD2MXKoSO3SJehCPsoCGaaKShDqpF4UJGUYxGdA0pTGh0wmNPRo6VFEcOyVt4gCt4ofETNiQvVUHQ1IiHTrMwhE197aVNMqcMZnEHjBWQLQ3JLdRRmzUXQqskMC@oiTJYoq7CCLXG94S0KA6uSVJRNIxyEvH9BZIKPFCx89c6sIAF4nvhVcKdcYRMUOibtRVUI3TFla3cNWNkvnVbVxNoiCg5tCbIkyZ3KbjKNxeWH1x8Orp9wdPj/vPXx0dv2nVlc4/XRyft9QN/cYhptPErRuqArtmhiO@HY4ye0R1405ZY/LUEtmY51IlG/UK2WCcwEPgMFXivs7C0AtHhG3mwZayNgCXgxy2kXaUpZMsFbhizx9jet1GFzkpdSWbxXUz9JU1cMA6cYIJ4WyIBJIHD1YDgGofDR0qa5zvb@MIdONYVfKMTt0smDQAOp26RCo39JS1BauBtfQFG5TrhpHv2iSXv9vQMbY4E@Pyd@hjZoS2DKF7DKJxmk6ShmWNvHScDapOFFgX8e3z9DSEYKBWGt96aSTHlFqBnUAIWzexPYEgToCDdBBR8aCoRGUqsLEygx0BwA1cYsZZyMK7CDzHCAGEOIPjZUWT1GIxw9@r8WCJoN1sA7oMMEYx9JIxe8NIX8Q/BGyG5Zip41gDL7Tgc7Uyh3DUncj2cxIxzwerBPzgBYB/7QX5EYZxNYUQaFsuvbbCzPfJVvtBHWMD/SLARR6ng/eYLK6pieqOUL8pifJFh/M1o@IaEwEsq9bCYpFxnkN25Z4G@QqzxXAw8Ja2NMs8C1SMBMZcn48ktT0fT1R5e69IfwLhcnR6Tg5PX5Kh59OCw3j2KCI/jfwVPh1FPnNrEjtyvMr434fFDU5u2YSYZpK6rb1dGGQC4ct7fLxkmcdmkA49C9@Ag1z8Moedn@GQL@8s8RjEthcOM@cqZyEXZqMloov4Zzadxl/YNONpDn17Xt7YBnkdHD2zhTxiHswRQupU@ccS02d2ckV9nx1iYMUmS0gfGP2HFeQ0iN57i@5ni/x9lduFyHIHVs5srKxhMi/ffFOELZ/0chkPWrmMB82BD3nAnMlkdrDEpEh4HESpF0aB50QhJrzpJIpT8ur06Lh/dnDxrHWpWlkSW743sEJg2YcynPk0uVSRI67k@8vZzE2q75eVvWK2u1phO5e7xV3lllmU/OII/0rkHPieM5@nbVyxoJzQeBJTeF@VrX@T2e7fosfvZ3RLPPf2JJ@9PQsqPE1v8V3gKazEDYl2GTZBrzbrKtpa3pJg/ceGzMGqGE1oqGuIoRnVmNqubjQYve5gjxXFru4Y7db2FvZ2fNasbz3GmQPeTIGH1mw/2NCoD33gUHtQuuNY9/tahYZuS9OgMkuNmhbTpWmhXpfhZXjGqnEDhxprB0V5FgTqZdiFikw8qOWsDq/3uhfPT3uI/4pOU@g4kxtoKoMMulTUhk4dCj0IdgisIWrXt7e/5cPN@rZVrzX4pPywZhi8W6ois1JJNiA4UxVsQVDVjwlw0xLrnUXgZWkF2zJFGnkPga0inD6rVJpZmrePnz9fR55LrE3zzjRJafx6/Y35hJy9G//445snT2pHpHakjq/54tsxKb95RNSX6y8J9cEBL08PyfnpEaXxycZ9GV7dTcuyLhVilUkJPiAf0dAOICg2dHQfdrEEzBs51saGRafQTmLvtt9oNrXj0xONlNrtS6VeBiZk6XV6qVib5FejkfM08H741du3@1EUqX70VN3/tlX75ny9XoeFJutAlJJLhxh059hg8JdlHSglbwgA0u87Ez9L8M@yfIUMdWO/KMqyPEDlLXjTgbztRW3Lcgpcy2Xga1lUgRBLi@qCaAgsb5gvXVZnUk873x32@0XlTHrtpQ59PziVhArcE7wQemruTP3csDYtseQFLJ2BQlWm1D40b9Wb2Euptblp7d9bm/dNpU3ItbK3t0f432yIo@tmW7kmBEw0q1EV@Xp8u21eMwald0@vlxzwpKJ21D4kLqB4osDCdbPbV3uFbqSds6o8aSJGu9Qs1uE2eXe98bRWq6MODE19vGfSUZgNaUcl/WWnc3U4x9I8Qeza2W/U/nVpHVnW6rAzqefsVUC/UAGj6heYV/EPI/buvvfpj//6l//79If/9e3Iie3x4V/@g8Wz2cSPcrvXlMNys/DebgOkKQDlatuE/6ZZbTZNfFXLEsCnbVPCAbXd1mcvA/8Zd/f5fz6TkBzW1fVur9uTOD0DphzIPgGKYACwdcYaF4ACcBgW4hoC@46Y9/2Waqj7@rrRSujv9zHOPvo0JYN1AKgtuKCcp/GGrqrrahJCGUntM7iHd8qqUS57oZeqvk@vEvuZrt6ZimVdfBd7G7sH/sdv/Q8te6tm3pumgRb@65/@@c/e@yigOPj0b//@1z/9y38XazXM/@fTT//16ac/f/rpP59Urmx1Vzou/F79PIyjgHyAqk34EdhUxFHADLPzUBm2fDsYuDYJG6xmhBUtHuQ1Q3FbAw17o8vpcIh/Wnmoa1V2lYcsqBnlgTYD8bFWfR/BmRvqJwaWoxM4511eiSoaz5ww4N0yDIoXaa1nKE4LrmtQRpIEmn99r3J0fPLi4OL4qGK@PHjT/23n@cU5rvVfHr/svzj@4fhFpWbw7K3zHVUHOw9piPJ0pyp56a5RdqpDyFpj3agMtCcWbNGlDAv2mqSxN9G1lmYYn0sEGnzT964ome7ukAB8Fdg@oUHm2yk@71h4WALJHB8z5E9WbqL4KiFjGtMK1rcbD3o2XMOqDEb1kX0FrB/HeIUfZKOEMwFcN6JJqHEWggM@DIGsP7AH/i0JsQamEVTDFBIeUMwemDDQmPoTEJiOBQYKSMdeQuwB7NBmzx4qBPpIElD5eMRB@0NpJhF0BZBZ4SO4FfUXFkPOAK6JEK6QixQZPsltorDYYg81oshPRICRiR2nnu0rCtOk0IjwyAL5ZNhQ1mBXo9gOSIsMZbAF0C9CV9Ai3VegSm9z59Gj7R2x2t16tNOAvzKooQtaowe4Yqy41M/HSkxHHt7pE0C4056faQ1Sm9ZrtQrRzp8XJodv2KRWOzmpKGvaEU5RNuKdzcZHz@UYkA4kDePQKZB0JMm9AjeRERd@eAKLJza0UYBxWpy8LU7Oi5OzfHKvKFgAaRxHsR4kI4NZDqN9qB6/fn36ukHuYPkePvI9r8f3qqGsgYeqdOqlet3gTEY07aMj@tgf6cgJB6CksHDOoIsW6/XYwyCGAhGA22oIPTToP5wsxfDKQl6RXcFEA8ELfEi5Req4mmZxyPgtqHODnSWq40egzIKWytrYW7Uq2OkAbTbJrkHKxI8U5fXx03MMIPQS9y@6j7132Du4lXuKhwJ3bg/pnh28OEHaO@ljnTNhfjAqpEQOXgDokIMO50GHL2T46FzcDHSEoA4HdeZBHQSxQBOyLuJMiHqGRGczUTnkECEsiIWkHHKEkKPnM0E5pPNMEYEEyTDyr9ntLQ52mdXjoALLI9j5HLC@g2bGxJR4YZLaoUN1RIVMglRABhTSbN046DHHz63RUS93lJCyQgsUBAzZeJWnOwfnx@jSrvQg@KtC5OxIzs7mYGdFmFwt4EoOGOWQBvsyZrn@512uDbSiu@Qbsttj6rGjItehdHIT8BVAYsbiaC2yzUzEt84YgoEqpChJWcOrFaJh3QJGNRhiwUQrQnLGbSMVYiDn2alCuy4dySxMoPnItwEMPCgAMXVScTKJ7ThQCfGACpHl1gJTqcsDUAYK@XCoKGvFTdVyXQKc7rCp3OXCcV7c7Fq@3ZwCZfGgQGBBTp2hyRPOdV2MC4M8EEouScoF2UlCoSBJtltf48q1/iJXmbF24TY26kdxH4yKUbtwPnIYkGcTn/KTQkcVMvZGY3bEJAYAXDu1ecTDGQCIwc2NqEULMDQIOVa0ivsrwr@RYAkVzGe5XcjtcSEMLIOIuYfF0VDFWswzOwaUjJ0U2N/NmDRqW1NWZIo6cCMl80aqMNDfbarId79mqUQCKkRnO5M1AemEaYyi6QoEDJ9jcuczVIm5bD/QA2zjjaDo7TJhs/LKWf6i8JBpVLhp7iD@TZ7Kj37BTcsuyvfFau3K4GD1dgkCFqoLhYBUqEMgXQH6Py6MFsu5CKg5u/6SiMqL1CqzFhwIjLkH5@2yCJ6dLm6dJXjhdK4MGNjLCgizKUDHntipCCrJXuxRTkkbhDweNmYLZkuKFfaTkCI/UPLrDIerWH6R6Sz2ZzwFomAhjTWHDlr8DL6kQIfG/feO00/GcJ/Q4Y7renh14ZT@qh6B1Uc/NxCOZ7bx8FsdwaNBVnSngF4U7cFVr77T344mrDFJYqcOMZekqzskBAMk3yVPA7hqcOjWAnSu3uCOksxH3ozRJn5sFXtoELwQsZwCSNklo4s3jF5RxjytQdaZ3kCSU7zlFAX64v6nUcw7QyCvoD6LG99l@8Y8zzBGYmSQd3wMJIZIihO4cctT0pi7GpyfMR24uXBmEBNLdH7ci4iVxRMn2UcT0T7O1dICU9B0@XqDLFE4Zq0vweXh5DjLii@jbynL1VBEFNzX2NnD7xTibJJ@IYYLcIzeLdZw5fc4XpZWoLF@Ce/hnO2uXrxNGOI2gfw5DtLU9li2Ft/lt4imsYbJdeOZT@B2wZrFm7HnU8aMt28hvQEkZxzrTBgSGQyR0/PrHm8UGSpw34BLyQBKwhUDCKmACHBc4Tdaviy/XShWa1FUtO9DL4BWAR9YsB94pFt1kv@oAioLjllN0QoZ/YvEwoZAl09yYoU5LhO/c2GXQjC02yD8aVlDVCVu51E@xhhePOIVJN2uNQqniy89@nlu71ZxK4HKD2sgqTZ9dII/lYHtDKgf3SDXnd0ZV3H4Viq0s9dYSncM8HhnxmAxFRcTDpT@QjbhTB23MYt4vHLKicOvhuJRI0wapNCBzdo6PHSGoHLpL6YyZ1S452WymSUESY4eTb4qRCQYQ8GbGdyo6LQiL2g0zAIa23B48YKHx5v9HIpdagrRg6gfvIke2@GI6ui5CjhuB9534ZLULVpI0Imdy5nYUT5lGvdYe1MM0q640TAl2YMx/hxOLyAx3SF1zp1oBl@VkNL4FoWM7dD12c14ThybQEeIX83BKfo1vT3Gg1Y4cWoWXoXRTVika/DjBvO89xP8dePz4gPD/Fmhwy/f8kFhNZn4kA@1yxCOKj73Q3jXhHRdAookC/iDT8p/pcW/AffEw0wKnoZSjl86Kqkdw6aBsXqQeI3dcqOxVW48fLxpBpV9Vclzo6py71ecebdzctYitPiXo@b2Fo8CHzFRbkO0zLAn34D@xGskJkP2u16P48@yIabU5Ju9R@XtLflMm/@MiLNSK@KHT/8P)

Next answer must not exceed 1543 bytes.

### Explanation

**Befunge-93** didn't like the `999` in it's path, so I changed its control-flow a little. The rest is very simple **99** code:

```
999 999 99  -- set 999 = 999 - 99 (900)
999 999 9   -- set 999 = 900 -  9 (891)
999         -- print 891/9        ( 99)
```

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020  .>  #^Gv        
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22           @,"B"_"
00000230: 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d  Tr",,@.   v<[_"]
00000240: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c  Befunge-93">,,,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,,,@<.   >#<"
00000260: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
00000270: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
00000280: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
000002a0: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c2c 2c2c 2237  >  ,,,,,@#,,,,"7
000002b0: 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7264 6175 5122 5f76  9-egnuferdauQ"_v
000002c0: 2321 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  #!$G0001<>.     
000002d0: 2040 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739   @,,,,,,,,,,,"79
000002e0: 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 3c3e 0a2e 6c20  -egnuferT"<>..l 
000002f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2e20 2020 2e2a            .   .*
00000300: 2f2f 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2 81b5 6c61  ///{}]........la
00000310: 6f63 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b  ocrahC..++++[-<+
00000320: 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  ++++>]<[-<++++++
00000330: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d  <+++++<+++++>>>]
00000340: 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d  <<<+++++++.>-.>-
00000350: 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b  --.<<-----.+++++
00000360: 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d  +++.-----.>--.>-
00000370: 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828  --.<+.>>>(((((((
00000380: 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29  (((()()()){}){})
00000390: 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928  {}){}()){})((()(
000003a0: 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b  )()()){}){})[(([
000003b0: 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d  ][]){}){}()])([]
000003c0: 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d  ()){})[]())(([[]
000003d0: 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b  []()]([]()((((([
000003e0: 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b  ][][])){}{})[]){
000003f0: 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d  })))[]())({ -}_=
00000400: 2229 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e  ")";(!)=seq;main
00000410: 7c6c 6574 2062 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453  |let b!_=""=putS
00000420: 7472 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150  tr$(""!"snrettaP
00000430: 676e 6142 2b22 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c  gnaB+")++init"ll
00000440: 656b 7361 4828 227b 2d0a 2f2f 544a 7269  eksaH("{-.//TJri
00000450: 2438 416c 7c3f 6c7a 3d61 3230 2d7d 2d2d  $8Al|?lz=a20-}--
00000460: 292a 2f2f 2ff0 9f92 ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f  )*///....ijome..
00000470: 92ac e29e a1f0 9f98 ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f  .........Emotino
00000480: 6d69 636f 6ef0 9f98 b2e2 8faa e28f ace2  micon...........
00000490: 8fa9 402c 6b61 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665  ..@,ka"89-egnufe
000004a0: 6e55 22                                  nU"
```

Answer (score 5):

## 45. [Spoon](https://github.com/MarquisdeGeek/spoon), 3743 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M eliF MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///opfzzfzzfzzfzzzfzzfzfzfffzffzzzzzffzfzzzffzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzfffzzfzfzzzfzffff⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
.L    . .         *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>](()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-"NUb4`BJJndO-}--)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejzaciiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaceeacewuuuweejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `eliF MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86
- `NOOPS` in Spoon

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbchvHlc@cX8hLa0gLMwQGQ5ASRUIAwjslryQyoixpDUDwYKYBDDmYgecCkKKZcm2qVJuqrTiVB@/lYS1v7ab2kmxVXPHD1npflHf7H/gDyR9oz@nuueBCSXYyJGa6z71Pn76cxqBtBL3Xr@fJpmURg9CuEXVd4x4JPagNPOes63ghCWkQkp7huzQISPuMPLDpznN6fOK1pXmy7TmOMQgokbc9i8rEcC0ib/rdqE/dMJBJQM3Q9tyAdDyftGkYUp/Q0wH1beqaVJJMIyQ1YgKv5LhEC1iR3YrtDpknW7QTuV2qra9IoReZPTLwbRAsgWq7Q868iBhoe6ywQPrGCSVB5FNsRd@z7M4ZAQuKgzMSeCTsgb6wR8@AhRLbNZ3IohYUEEgc2z2RqNnziOYSeaEkg2mcNwNdRqjlBePQFYQGXr9PtY59Oo67gbjHxYERmj1JGpyFPc9dmU287xtBUJZCn2imRUZPhqTCfIN4bLPp9Qe2Q6F7WNNssH1I/QA8TLwO2fIN271jmCdEYcU9x3i6tkrox5E9NBzwjyq124joOAbQqORcIqR/YtnQNTFYa3uRCz4BjDkgujcIdYbrgVh9sdgLZpNaM8EB2KfZJBfoDaX@zNCeb2ofNhvqXTekXerrjRKUVpb1bo4sjlGHXkzS8b0@K/uGM02XYN9CuWzb/YHnh2THCI0iUHF0t2emPoOm8YYUi9JF1k813aJD3Y0chyzXrpckSbq3@WD/g8393dbdBzu7T6slaeuvH@0eVeUFZWRCx7EuU2UJIpcFP3EMtxsZXaqo59Ic62p5niyMSymShVKBLDBJMMpg0Mkx7cPIdW23S1hAXl@W5towbEEPC8aaF4WDKJTmIGbAuwScTCqEAyHseEFzTCGMBeR5qVC4kD/x6bCGY9EMobOErlk4zXWkORht14jZH6QSSYwn169fiQPe2zi2XGmOa3jie9AUTlgkd@ipFfUHZcCenlokbkvHluYmnAzOVSZcli@pauIkjTQ@WlBwOuFC1MZHOKyZz2rxrHGBY6gXhoOgrOtdO@xF7SIMKf2Rf3Y3PHBh/FM99M/s0IvLlOp9I4BZSx/5xgDmrUCKe5PIOzKRrT6EmB@5bM6SM8gjHN9A4EcwZ7JxxEY8vxf99hRDrVID8nh6YBwdO@ixG05fk/TbQM2oTC00Tb1tuzo8ZxuzDfO36RlOwiLqSWGWgsd2H@iHdj@Zl6FcDKGfJ4YEBgB6XqCzMg7a7@MKMKQamttF@06J1z4WQJPL1bwsjKkAkUV9ApgVnCwMa3Gb2gmE@aLTbttTTUqXkwkuxgJlbs8nJDRsB4dYfmU9y78HAbFzcES2D@6TDkzEmQ7jS0KWeN9zZvRp13NYtwa@GZdnOf8DN9vAwRmrEE0LQqu6vgaFSBBc3cZbU565pfXDjq3jDSTEwKslrL5FQgJenZLB58/IPElExIC0NMX0yH9Lo0P/ikYzmRrO12P62KqVLos82DbHGGEulfljSugdIzihjsMGMYhilSmi54z/@Qx22veO7cnuZ0B@n9XtQmV@CyCHBm6X3GBcv/Y0i5se6fk8DrR8HgeaCY94gJmDQTqwRCXLuNv3Qtv1@rbpuSABJnBcMB8c7Oy2Djcf3ak2ZD0KfN2x27oLIluwAYkcGjRklIiQpH2JmLFK8Xja2BPmu5MZvrN4t1izuiWNkneO8DdEzqZjm@PztIEQHRYM6g98CvdZs/VPIsP6IXZ8nPJNyVxfj@Wsr@uw5NPwDO8zdKNxP0R3wjclMzjrtz1oOMkO3L7nemLtanfwU6SnnHXWEsCo2dYdqMaWQqh/f2uDmGvaVlifaRBL4jU9hCSAhrpPHWoEVECnV2U6CH@QLYOrHLeHuzzPtmJhHVFPClMcbJM/FnFdhPD7rFgznEFv5kwqEKRou7idgs3m2FSw@eDx5hFwpaPTNNyhEbABPGs8ukYf3AdpXgyKVcYI3bIDMCCyHSuFJVxTE@DQxsnz2BgasJY60DrIgXpingAcYbepbQew4G5CZEywGPMnYxtqHZhTDP0xZiIwq7HnjFjMTJiMZNZ64Tg061Koxs/pFTFNp@R4bcukOpklRtucjrmBx6dU3Kg@ODg4PJJ5wscxpB9Bgt2mLNGG3XTfcCPDcc7ICDaos3ar9w0fRnJg0X1KT/QAZRQIpNcDTBKOXA/2ut093@vKkGzivrdDcg23AlNZjWUmtVySg2IOgYm5iVtlb0BdJYcUObXoU8NS1DLjV0zMtT3fUky1Vl1Zxhyf1yql5VtYM2EBCEFGrlK7vpCjTkBJJ3d9/pxTXdzOFahrVXM52K7HFlV0ZktFR7sabsM9ZFv0MhZz7FhA7NkFg9xw67BNJzZs8Nnm/Fqz/ujuQRPpH9DTkBhuMKI@dyZaQ09NCt7EtIElVbXSysqPeXGxtKKXlsq8kr@xpKo84yqisPn5OCvBmixhXoKmfoLJJOScz3QCl57L@JYZUk66Co8MIP70@fnU0/wY4fXrIU4I@qJ2rmlkvvfw2lNtgxw@6/30p083NpZ2yNKO3Bty4Ic9kn96k8j3r90n1LH3yP2DbXJ0sEOpv7dwkYervqjrEL2d58@Tf/6Avw5@nuOFpcyD/T2fqiBDCoXr8uWLyy9fvMu9IRE9T@bhAZsoipMBpJEKBhCepxDoYM/UFxZ0mM5VlljeLlcqud2DvRyZr9UaUikPzSBT10FD0hfJj7pdc79vP/7Rhx/e9jxPdrx9@faPq0vvHV0rlQBQYWmTNG/RDq6UR5gV8UvXN6V5uwMI0mqZAycK8KPrjkQ6ino7q0rXbSDlh0EVEzabtlfTdTMjNZ8HubpOJQjyMGsuqIbQtjsJqFFMtR5svb/damWN02DGC036fvsgZpRgvNuuop7zcFKOVH1RFyBxaAEGFZlRtyHjLI58O6T64qJ@@0JfvKhINUKGoydwsduTEVZG37/wZJReibD4kTyzpfHKGPwKyDuCnoxmAZ8ktl2BenI1il/S@vo64Z@0iKVhpbYEV6mE/9KQEAipNBEpxNetsxVtWCEb6PL5Z/vDqZDdKMhbcgv2p8CzIQFgWKm35GYm6awlwgpLn2xUkKY2X8kmXDXybLiwD8agHYxQvrWu0a4bdeiWTFrTA2XIYoCRbsxzUIbHfyS3hvMERS6VKjWJvPGq1Eroif2FISec3yiMXRvzGcmWEf1EbjGGlOPKK9uQ0LVTVuC9NhzT8xZJ41dG6oAegfvHdpvjDdiYf6ts6PqhDJ0HfbknF@QIPi58TPiE8PHgY8PHkis14sOKYHkjl4Qjj1Uc2sHliZIz2Hh4IxINSNen1OVUM4HIBpCwByBW8e1uL2QSBX2Wl5XbTkS5qgk5rJBR/w7Ub7D8nYQkfKlE1pLvbTv6AGyZ6a7ZAv4sz7HhzuKPB2FprIT3bC1L8S7003TTcjK40hXyS2@SuPQWje@gN8aU0nvyyJamPgmB8CEnLvFaKeUVZCkuy5Mh@d7PWFGsckb7SlM8P1CfaKpUvIfzQxH@4gv3X@cXzctf/NMfv/n1q/9xDM/0jd72q/@6/PyrV8nf5d/9zeWLf//2d3D7wxdwS2GXL34JkJ//6@Xn31y@@BW7//Ly5/@GZYb/7mdYFP@MOa1992mmJmCvvvzDF6@@TKrf/n4GI6P7epzruxdI/TWIZGrHxQiST8GYz7@KCb772auvBQnUvv1dWv7uUygDIfsfKzIBQPx7pjCGc9jX2PjPv3n15av/zdc1trnVKvjI15qVuJivZO61GmAqApEv1jT417RipaLhVczHCF6taTEeSIFTUdT4T63UFPE8V84v6oraRBCW1bh@AeVK7YJRniNEqZxfKOnFBQFR/M9rSqJGIOqKUm/WmzFNU4UqR7InYBGN8vHORCMAOICGUSGtyqlrzKxzEFRRxq@/kDl1ZoSKCCBKarzO/hjPuM6s4jonZoYq50S7aFVlVb6tXFOrAf34Nu5yP3Eo5L7XACFXB1F4FPoLiixfkwPXp2FoHHZdYysvq/m87dqhDKn5SWDcUeRzTdL1O3ceafKDD9o3Ptp6/33XOtAuNE2ta81KrVFvwK2hw01v1HW4VWr4x8sMzB7xX6PR1BkI0VhsNIp6M4Dxffm3/3i0@fjB5vYf/@@Xf/riV7@xj70@xcLlP3/5py/@4bfZU1Oof3X52X9efvaby8/@Y6NwYshr8dbE/SDAy8CLJtcgUzbtIK4d2@I6plPX8XPDtLMX0hgm@4yiKBoJ9uNJErhO@AM2/ZcvP718@fnly7@/fPmLy3@B/1/j/8v/ll/jt6jkuWO3CU8@FiWRhGBut3pD6lQdo9@2DOKW2XmBW8j57eS8QLKq7RwepTdOOx385PIdJVdkZ4KQAefUfDuXong5Vzz2INvpKHsqHkXsQYZV56cQhRzPmqHAv1yBQvZbc6iKM6JcU5XMKn457tMg8NrHynphZ3fv3uaj3Z2Cdn/zaevJ1t1HRwhr3d@937q3@3j3XmFJ5Tm8wttWbK/eoC5qVsxiLEux1LxZ7EDm2FPUQju3oUNjLcqooNVB6NsDJVfNqerrebJzcKQ59gklp2urpA8R2zccQvuRY4T49sPEqxN2h710kLxnMfL8k4D0qE8LeMoxsh2HwfBsBtzroPgC9IOP5zukHXUDLgRoLY8Gbo6LEBLw1QjIvNtG2zkjLp6EhB6hpyEkncCRvj7BUD3qDPhxE6dABWHPDojRhhYa7FvsAjGCE9Kn8csSJvaEGwb44gFuAOHRPxOnMAB0uQCzZ8Cghc24FAdScBZILMr4@ajnBCLUyMDwQ9twJIlZkjmO4jEG@kmnLM1Bq7q@0SdV0onDrk/7nn8GkPoDMKW5uHrz5sqqgNaXb66W4ZMHMxTBqzaBVpQlizpJWfJp18avewMgOM/dPcyVydIpbAAKJHd0N1PZfsoqS0t7ewVpLreDVdSNdIdpeeduXAaizZiHSdjKsGzFLBdSxzG6XPn2HgD3DCdAioNs5cNs5ShbOUwqF5KEhxDU9z1f6QddlXkOo70j7z58ePCwTM4BfAGPpM3X/AtZleagh4r01A6VksqFdGnYwo5o4SmZgpKwAEYKDycC6uixZpO9LcBIIAKwWWVhRw5SMzMKMbzw3BRPRSwhJAeKJ@SQfJWUEBpGvsvkTZgzwvNFNMfxwJgJK6W5nj0LKsQpgK1UyJpK8sTxJOnh7v4RBhD2Eu9f7D5232J36FbeUzwUeOc2ke/O5r095D2P@1jhQlg/qAUyTzbvAWqbo7bHUdv34vBRuLoUtYOoLY7aGkdtIYoFmtD1yI@EqjvIdJiqSjDbiGFBLDQlmB3E7NxNFSWYrTuSCCSYDD1nyL728/trzOt@vwDgLrR8DFlaRTfjxBTYbhAarkkVJIWZBLmADThit9X9fpN1/BiMdptJRwktM6xARSCQlWf19Nbm0S52aT3uQeivAolrO3HtcAx3mMXF0AxtLAGjHKbBVhyz3P6jOrdG18kaeY@sNZl5bKjEcFhEuQs4BIiYszhZlawwF/GmM4HgoALJapLm8IAdyXDdAkFLUMSlE70IkzM2G7mQAiWnowr9OjUkIzegYUKEAmxYAHxqhmJkEsM0YSXEASpU5qsTQmNbroMxp3h6LElz2UYtJbb0sbrKqnErJ4bzZGPnkuYmHKiLBwUiM3pKjCwe4dzWybhQyXVh5JSmRJERBBQWpFjs8pukcquvlBrPWGsKgFqe3wKnYtROjI8EB@zRwKF8pNBugfTsbo8NsZgCEJYRGjziYQwARuXuRtKsBxgZhBxbtLLty@Lfi9ExVghP53aht8mVMHQcRKx7WBx1ZFyL@cyOARXHTgjiz1Mh5aXlU7bIZG3gTgrGnVRgqD/bVZ5jvclTQYwoEIW1LF4TkE@4Rs26LsPA6Dkl73xGGlNO@w/sAN/YXVj01piydHnlIt8pPOJpVHTT2ED8QT2VDP1MN013UdIuttbODA623k5hwEMlYRCwCnPw60og/8uF0eRyLgJqzK/vElHJIjXLrZkOBMG8B8f9MolORxf3zhQ@MzpnBgy0ZQaG@RSwPVu0VARVLF60Ma6SGii51SmnAK0aqxX@izFZeWDkmwV2Zom8Umga@6lMQShExM4aIwcr3kIfc2CH@q1j02wFPcgnFEjJLRtTF87pzNojsPXRSRyE5dQ3Nr4OKGSUyYzdKZBnVduQ6pVWWyvegG1MAt8sQcwF4ewdEqIBk7SSTwMIVTl2eQI7tt5gi4LIQdlM0CI@lrN7aFA8EbGcA1hZklHHDKOZ1THOq5JrzG5gSTg@5BwZ/mz7Tz2f7wyBvYD2TDZ8jbUb53lG0RUllTzjZWBRxaQ4gIw7HiXlsdTg6JDZwN2FNZVouEQnwz1LWJgccbF4byC2j2NraUYoWDqd3qBIVI6z1lX4eHBymmnDp8mXpenVUEQU5Gts7OHLaH40CK@I4Qweo3eZbbiSPI4vSzPI2H4J83Audk3JZhOqyCZQPqdBnqV1NluLF8yrJJdjGybL8tM@geyCbRZHPfytAgrj2zeXjoDI7PkKU4ZMKiPk/Dzd4xtFRgrSFyApacOScMIQQisQAh4hPKPl4Pgdk@xqLRaV3Aeu3YetAh5YsJ97hMslkryeDysLltmaksvM6FcyCx8CX1JJmCXWcZH41QtLCsHRVpnwc7OyWJW4n7tJGWN4cogXkHVlqZwZXRx08@3Sns2SNg8m31gCTUunN/fwhzPQnDZ1vBFKXV1LpYrBN9Og1fXy1HTHELdWUwGTU3F2woGlPzObcKGmVU4jHlPOuGLy1FAcOkKlTDI7sHRbh4NOFVwWfWcuLeXCNk@zpZ4QLAm5N3ijEjHBqBJmZpBR0dNCnKBRN@pT34DBiwkeDm/24yiW1GSiB0mf2wPFN9wuVbDnCtBxq3BfgySpnvWQ4BMtj2uiRUmVWdxk25tskNZFRsOMZAdj/BxOyRAx22HqHBvRDD9rQgr9M1TSM1zLYZnxmDpWgR0hvqAFo@iv6NkuDrTMiJMj98TF72szfGU@3KCe7P2EfAWPXg98u2u7hkOSoWowH7bPyEZ66grbRPGOFtqLb98XYQ9onoApPfQye73O0Eurt27duKnfWCutr4n1omOfttjZs4KckHmwt00LxHGrOM@DUyWCR6qOm25q8StCqMMspus5cLCCJ5CckS1Z6mKO5JAPRdY1tmgAPUy7kH9GfX4IS9nhLJbZa7c2O1oNKO5LIPRgb4HvwqGQZEaWZayysCuY4/EmlHPTgip/PU9bWWZ15HCQHhWVxXsS2CSw2lFhi2SXA43xOHW7mbClczJO7MF76zfzK8sqmiDWNPGjnqlT3fhAl7c/c5xbDAYOrFq5hptj3ndSB036hnVJ1jPsZ3ypWyTeYvTKZmCX1/Ll8nK@fOPWotYv3JalyB0ZbFIH/FLJMKl97A0CRT2/qDfxlxugDgTC6MCfyQR86u9Qn5KRTjzA@Fy1Er8BWyCb4o3c6/yHZdqeY5xAI5hJ1SuiCPAB9GYaKDnxnUjfGChiejHLRCZFuc46NDa7WWBtVdX6crn5Zh2wHXMtVbwQqvAfJ/GOliHzRdZ6eRn3IkCG0hi9ADEswFT19epKYfWWuboiVZIvwSFCKPuFV9zfMP/hbxKhczCdglxOJeyNUMvLcOFlkopGevs0xF8nkd4kFmclk3idCTheuWs5otVmKeypM8hbSNwdEMUsB6qkaRq@MPV9zU8NJbVaFcUViYLy/h8)

Next answer must not exceed 4865 bytes.

### Explanation

Spoon is just brainfuck, but it uses stings of 1 and 0 as tokens. However, the interpreter lets you change the 0s and 1s to any other ascii characters (it sadly crashes with unicode), so for this polyglot I've set 0=z and 1=f (those letters were chosen because they play fairly well with alphuck and evil).

Since the Spoon interpreter can't handle unicode, we have to make sure Spoon is terminated before any unicode characters are encountered (or fork/fix the interpreter). Currently, it's near the end of the first line, so this shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Note that Spoon must currently be tested manually. There is an interpreter [on Github](https://github.com/MarquisdeGeek/spoon) or you can ping me in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development) and if I'm online I can test it for you. This answer uses `spoon.exe /0z /1f polyglot` as the interpreter command.

Also, I trimmed down the evil code a bit by mixing it in to the alphuck that it was previously adjacent to. Only saved 5 characters, but may as well keep the byte count low where we can.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6946 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M eliF MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 7066 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a7a 667a 7a7a  /opfzzfzzfzzfzzz
00000060: 667a 7a66 7a66 7a66 6666 7a66 667a 7a7a  fzzfzfzfffzffzzz
00000070: 7a7a 6666 7a66 7a7a 7a66 667a 667a 7a7a  zzffzfzzzffzfzzz
00000080: 667a 667a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a7a 7a66 7a66  fzfzfzzfzfzzzfzf
00000090: 7a66 7a7a 667a 667a 6666 667a 7a66 7a66  zfzzfzfzfffzzfzf
000000a0: 7a7a 7a66 7a66 6666 66e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  zzzfzffff.......
000000b0: a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1  ................
000000c0: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086  ................
000000d0: e2a1 865c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  ...\. /+ #\. bas
000000e0: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
000000f0: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000100: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000110: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
00000130: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
00000140: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
00000150: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
00000160: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
00000170: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000180: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000190: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
000001a0: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
000001b0: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
000001c0: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
000001d0: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
000001e0: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
000001f0: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000200: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000210: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
00000220: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
00000230: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
00000240: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
00000250: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
00000260: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
00000270: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000280: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000290: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
000002a0: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
000002c0: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000300: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000320: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
00000330: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
00000340: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000350: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
00000360: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000370: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000380: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000390: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
000003a0: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
000003b0: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
000003c0: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
000003e0: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
000003f0: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000400: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000410: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
00000420: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
00000440: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
00000450: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
00000470: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000480: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
000004a0: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
000004b0: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
000004c0: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
000004d0: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000500: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000510: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
00000560: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
00000570: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000580: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000590: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005a0: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22   <>"v"@. @,"F","
000005b0: 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22  u","n","c","t","
000005c0: 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564  o","i","d"<> red
000005d0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
000005e0: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
000005f0: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000600: 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  ow up green down
00000610: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
00000620: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
00000630: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
00000640: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
00000650: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77  een down red dow
00000660: 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  n one yellow dow
00000670: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000680: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000690: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
000006a0: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
000006b0: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
000006c0: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
000006d0: 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77  left one red dow
000006e0: 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  n three yellow d
000006f0: 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  own yellow down 
00000700: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000710: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20  down red up two 
00000720: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  green down yello
00000730: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
00000740: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075   blue left red u
00000750: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
00000760: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
00000770: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000780: 7565 206c 6566 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030  ue left 00011100
00000790: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
000007b0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
000007c0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
000007e0: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030  1000100010000000
00000800: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000810: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000110000100010
00000820: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030  0010000010001100
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000840: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000850: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000860: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000870: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000880: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000890: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030  0000110000110000
000008a0: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030  0110000010011000
000008b0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010001000100010
000008c0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031  0010000001001101
000008d0: 3131 3030 3030 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131  1100000011001111
000008e0: 3030 3031 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030  0001100110000000
000008f0: 3130 3031 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030  1001110011110000
00000900: 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  1101110000010000
00000910: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000920: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000930: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000940: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031  0001000110001101
00000950: 3131 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  1110001000100010
00000960: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031  0000100010100001
00000970: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0000000100010000
00000980: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000990: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000009a0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000009b0: 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 0a2e 4c20 2020  0000100110..L   
000009c0: 202e 202e 2020 2020 2020 2020 202a 2f2f   . .         *//
000009d0: 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63  /{}]........laoc
000009e0: 7261 6843 c2ab e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2  rahC............
000009f0: b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000a00: e286 a8c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690  ................
00000a10: c39f e289 a4e2 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286  ................
00000a20: 90e2 89a5 e286 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2  ................
00000a30: 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692  ................
00000a40: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a50: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3  ................
00000a60: 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286  ................
00000a70: 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000a80: 8692 e286 a8c2 b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a90: e286 a8c2 a1cf 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c  ................
00000aa0: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000ab0: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2  ................
00000ac0: 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692  ................
00000ad0: e286 a8c2 a1ce b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000ae0: a1cf 80c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1  ................
00000af0: e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2  ................
00000b00: c2a1 ceb4 c2a1 cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000b10: b2e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1  ................
00000b20: c2bb 2b5b 2d2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  ..+[-++++[-<++++
00000b30: 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  +>]<[-<++++++<++
00000b40: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c  +++<+++++>>>]<<<
00000b50: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
00000b60: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
00000b70: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
00000b80: 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 5d28 2829 2829 2829 2829  <+.>>>](()()()()
00000b90: 2829 293c 3e28 2829 2829 293c 3e7b 287b  ())<>(()())<>{({
00000ba0: 7d5b 2829 5d29 3c3e 287b 287b 7d29 287b  }[()])<>({({})({
00000bb0: 7d5b 2829 5d29 7d7b 7d29 3c3e 7d3c 3e28  }[()])}{})<>}<>(
00000bc0: 2829 7b5b 2829 5d28 3c7b 7d28 2828 2828  (){[()](<{}(((((
00000bd0: 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b  (((((()()()){}){
00000be0: 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828  }){}){}()){})(((
00000bf0: 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28  )()()()){}){})[(
00000c00: 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928  ([][]){}){}()])(
00000c10: 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b  []()){})[]())(([
00000c20: 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828  [][]()]([]()((((
00000c30: 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d  ([][][])){}{})[]
00000c40: 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 293e 297d 7b7d  ){})))[]())>)}{}
00000c50: 297b 7b7d 283c 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  ){{}(<((((((((((
00000c60: 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d  ((((()()()){}){}
00000c70: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829  ){}){}()){})((()
00000c80: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828  ()()()){}){})[((
00000c90: 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b  [][]){}){}()])([
00000ca0: 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 5b5b 5d28  ]()){})[]())[[](
00000cb0: 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d29 5b5b 5d28 2928  )()()])[])[[]()(
00000cc0: 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d5b 5d5b 5d5b 2829  )()()])[][][][()
00000cd0: 5d29 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b  ])((((((()()()){
00000ce0: 7d28 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2829  }()){}){}){})[()
00000cf0: 2829 5d29 3e29 7d7b 7d28 7b20 2d7d 5f3d  ()])>)}{}({ -}_=
00000d00: 2229 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e  ")";(!)=seq;main
00000d10: 7c6c 6574 2062 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453  |let b!_=""=putS
00000d20: 7472 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150  tr$(""!"snrettaP
00000d30: 676e 6142 2b22 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c  gnaB+")++init"ll
00000d40: 656b 7361 4828 227b 2d0a 2f2f 4848 542d  eksaH("{-.//HHT-
00000d50: 224e 5562 3460 424a 4a6e 644f 2d7d 2d2d  "NUb4`BJJndO-}--
00000d60: 295b 2d5d 3c3e 5c5b 5c3c 3e5c 5c2f 3c3e  )[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>
00000d70: 5c2f 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5b  \/\[/\/\<><><>\[
00000d80: 2f5c 2f5c 2f3c 3e5c 2f2f 5c2f 3c3e 3c3e  /\/\/<>\//\/<><>
00000d90: 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5c 5d2f 5c2f 2f5c 2f2f  <><><>\\]/\//\//
00000da0: 5c2f 5c5d 2f5c 2f5c 5c2e 2f5d 732a 2f2f  \/\]/\/\\./]s*//
00000db0: e288 9953 4156 4e41 43ef bd90 f09f 92ac  ...SAVNAC.......
00000dc0: 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad  ijome...........
00000dd0: 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2  Emotinomicon....
00000de0: e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839  .........@,ka"89
00000df0: 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5573 7373 7373 6161  -egnufenUsssssaa
00000e00: 6161 6165 6565 6565 6565 6565 6570 6165  aaaeeeeeeeeeepae
00000e10: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6563 6973 6165 6565  eeeeeeeeecisaeee
00000e20: 6565 6565 6a69 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565  eeeejiiiiiiiijee
00000e30: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
00000e40: 6a7a 6163 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969  jzaciiiiiiiiiiii
00000e50: 696a 6565 6561 6365 6561 6365 7775 7575  ijeeeaceeacewuuu
00000e60: 7765 656a 6969 6969 6a69 6969 6969 6969  weejiiiijiiiiiii
00000e70: 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6161 6161 6b65 6561  iiiijeeeaaaakeea
00000e80: 6161 6177 7677 e2a0 80e2 a096 e2a0 97e2  aaawvw..........
00000e90: a08e e2a2 8ee2 a2a6 e2a2 a6e2 a0ae 22    .............."
```

Comment: Its not really exactly a *Vesatile __Integer__ Printer*. I expect it to have a higher score on average than the other polyglot because the task is slightly more complex.

Comment: @Potato44 Completely forgot that when I was figuring the score lol. Good point. Looks like this polyglot is about the same size-wise as entry #113 in the other one.

Answer (score 5):

## 50. Alice & Bob, 4211 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M eliF MOC SODeerF$}++++-+[*///opfzzfzzfzzfzzzfzzfzfzfffzffzzzzzffzfzzzffzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzfffzzfzfzzzfzffff⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 & I8 H I  d      $$$
a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP<
>"gnalokniM"OOOOOOOOO.
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
01 & && &&&     & {}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩+-+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]>+{}[<<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>->-]<+[<<+.<++++++++++++.>>+.<+++.<--.>+.--------.<++++.>+.>>{}]>]<>(()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}<>{}{<>(((((()(((((()()()){}){}){}){}){})()(()()()()()){})[()()()])[(()()()){}])()())((((((()()()()){}){}){})(()()()){})[(()()()){}])((((()((((()()()){}){}){}){}){})()((()()()){}){})[()((()()()){}){}])<>(())}(()){{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())<>}<>>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")+;;+;+;+;+;;+;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;+;+;+;+;;;+;;+;;+;;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;;+;+";x--?y
 =y;y="yrruC";(!)=seq;main=let b!_=""in putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++y--?"lleksaH"
--N'Zi(Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*///∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejzaciiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaceeacewuuuweejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw;+;;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;;+;+;;;+;;+;⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `eliF MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86
- `NOOPS` in Spoon
- `yrruC` in Curry
- `gnalokniM` in Minkolang
- `epyhniarb` in Brainhype
- `kcufloob` in boolfuck
- `bob & ecila` in Alice & Bob

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbctvIlc/CL@SlDWlEQCQIUbJliSIZ3W3P2pZieWyvKZoBgSYJCQQYXEjRGk1NbaqmNlVbmak8zF4edma2dlN7SbYqU5mHrc2@OO@Zf9APJH/gPae7ceFFtmcSSAS6z71Pn76cJtgygu7r1/Nk27KIQWjHiDqucZ@EHtT6njPqOF5IQhqEpGv4Lg0C0hqRhzbde0lPz7yWNE92Pccx@gEl8q5nUZkYrkXkbb8T9agbBjIJqBnanhuQtueTFg1D6hN63qe@TV2TSpJphKRGTOCVHJdoASuyW7HVJvNkh7Yjt0O1jdUpfO/MAYIHtnvmOYbbkUIvMruk79ugWALT7DYZeRExsG2xQQXSM84oCSKfYit7nmW3RwQsLPZHJPBI2AV7wi4dAQsltms6kUUtKCCQOKBLombXI5pL5IWSDKZz3gx0BaGWF4xDVxEaeL0e1dr2@TjuJuKeFPtGaHYlqT8Ku567Opv4jm8EQVkKfaKZFhk@HZAK8x3isc2m1@vbDoXuY02zwfYB9QPoAeK1yY5v2O5dwzwjCiseOMaz9TVCfxLZA8MB/6hSq4WItmMAjUouJEJ6Z5YNXReDtZYXueATwJh9onv9UGe4LojVl4rdYDapNRMcgH2aTXKBfqLUXxjay23teeNEveeGtEN9/aQEpdUVvZMjS2PUoReTtH2vx8q@4UzTJdi3UK7Ydq/v@SHZM0KjCFQc3emaqc@gabwhxaJ0mfVTTbfoQHcjxyErtcWSJEn3tx/e@WD7zn7z3sO9/WfVkrTz14/3j6vygjI0oeNYl6myBJHNBgfB8I2MDlXUC2mOdbU8TxbGpRTJQqlAFpgkGIUwKOWY9lHkurbbISwgF1ekuRYMa9DDgrHmRWE/CqU5iBnwLgEnkwrhQAg7XtAcUwhjAXlRKhQu5Q99OqjhWDVD6CyhaxZOcx1pDkbbDWL2@qlEEuPJ4uK1OODdxLHlSnNcw1Pfg6ZwwiK5S8@tqNcvA/b83CJxW9q2NDfhZHCuMuGyfElVEydp5OTHCwpON1yIevJjHNbMZ7V41rjEMdQNw35Q1vWOHXajVhGGlP7YH90LD10Y/1QP/ZEdenGZUr1nBDCr6UPf6MO8FkhxbxJ5Tyay1YMQ8yOXzVlyBnmM4xsI/AjmVDaO2Ijn96LfmmKoVWpAHk8PjKNtB112w@lrkn4XqBmVqYWmqbdsV4fnbGN2YX43PcNJWEQ9KcxS8MTuAf3A7iXzMpSLIfTzxJDAAEDPC3RWxmHrfVwhBlRDczto3znxWqcCaHK5mpeFMRUgsqhPALOCk4VjPW5TK4EwX7RbLXuqSelyM8HFWKDM7fmQhIbt4BDLr25k@Q8gIPYOj8nu4QPShok402F8ScgS3/GcGX3a8RzWrYFvxuVZzv/AzTawP2IVomlBaFU31qEQCYLr23h7yjO3tV7YtnW8gYQYeL2EtbdISMBrUzL4/BmZZ4mIGJCWppge@29pdOhf02gmU8P5ekwfW7XSZZEH2/YYI8ylMn9MCb1rBGfUcdggBlGsMkX0kvG/nMFOe96pPdn9DMjvs7pdqMzvAOTIwO2UG4zr155lcdMjPZ/HgZbP40Az4REPMLPfTweWqGQZ93teaLtezzY9FyTABI4L5sPDvf3m0fbju9UTWY8CX3fslu6CyCZsQCKHBicySkRI0r5EzFileDpt7Bnz3dkM31m8W6xZ3ZJGyTtH@BsiZ9uxzfF52kCIDgsG9fs@hfus2fpHkWF9Hzt@kvJNydzYiOVsbOiw5NNwhPcZutG476M74ZuSGYx6LQ8aTrIDt@e5nli7Wm38FOk5Z521BDBqtnUHqrGlEOrf3dog5pq2FdZnGsSSeE0PIQmgoe5ThxoBFdDpVZn2w@9lS/86xx3gLs@zrVhYW9STwhQH2@SPRVwHIfw@K9YMp9@dOZMKBCnaLm6nYLM5NhVsP3yyfQxc6eg0DXdgBGwAzxqPrtED90EaGINilTFCt@wADIhsx0phCdfUBDiwcfI8NQYGrKUOtA5yoK6YJwBH2G1q2wEsuJsQGRMsxvzJ2AZaG@YUQ3@CmQjMauw5IxYzEyYjmbVeOA7NuhSq8XN6RUzTKTle2zKpTmaJ0banY67v8SkVN6oPDw@PjmWe8HEM6UWQgLcoS8RhN90z3MhwnBEZwgZ11m71geHDSA4seofSMz1AGQUC6Xcfk4Rj14O9bufA9zpjsRD5/ii2YeT70W5sA8O8mw3D4RAiDTL9nhHaZ8XItbUzmzpFi@of9Y0zM4BJ06LnxW7Yc1KLdh4cZi1JEvrJlbEXI9JSc7lYuhUvk3ggMNUn3VEfOxETPcgHLy71utbA7I/PUeKgISbEwHjjXiQlHYsVD7Zp2fEn6lhoz15PyCLZ8VqpYZbv9Z92YcO478LEYDuYUHQ2cSCG@w7t6RRvYHa6/kBotdge8QFYxIKcMMkgFmvjIZ7FaIYwSWJJT5vkTtwKrGM1lpbWcskBBCaQeGpjYp7k9amr5JAipxZ9aliKWmb8iokHLZ5vKaZaq66u4AEQr1VKK7exZsLqH4KMXKW2uJCjTkBJO7c4f8GpLjdzBepa1VwOcrXYoorObKnoaNeJe@IesfysjMUcOzMSCZtgkE/cOuRoxIbsjmVmNxr1x/cOG0j/kJ6HxHCDIfV5FKM19Nyk4HnMGVlGXSutrv6QF5dKq3ppucwr@ZvLqsrT7SIKm5@PU1KsyRImpWjqh6IfX@gELj2X8S0zpJyMETwvgp7R5@dTT/MzpNevB7ga6EvahaaR@e6jG8@0LXL0ovvRR8@2tpb3yPKe3B1w4PMuyT@7BYPlxgNCHfuAPDjcJceHe5T6BwuXebi0fH1J1yFe2i9fJv/8AX9t/LzEC0uZB/t7OVVBhhQK19WXn1x99cm73E8koufJPDxgD01xLSCQq2MI4XEagS72TH1hQYfVXGXnCpvlSiW3f3iQI/O12olUykMzyNR1eCLpS@QHnY55p2c/@cHz55ue58mOd0fe/GF1@b3jG6USACosa5bmLdrGjdIxJsX80vVtad5uA4I0m2bfiQL86LojkbaibmZV6boNpPwssGJCrmF7NV03M1LzeZCr61SCMA@z5oJqCG67nYBOiqnWw533d5vNrHEaLHihSd9vHcaMEky1tquoFzyglGNVX9IFSJxZgUFFZtSmvCcXh74dUn1pSd@81JcuK1KNkMHwKVzs9nSIleF3LzwdplciLH4kz2xpvDIGvwbyjqCnw1nAp4lt16CeXo/il7SxsUH4Jy1iaVCpLcNVKuG/NCAEQirNQwvxdXu0qg0qZAtdPv/izmAqZLcK8o7chPQEeLYkAAwq9abcyJw51BJhheUPtypIU5uvZPPtGnkxWLgDxqAdjFC@vaHRjhu16Y5MmtMDZcBigJFuzXNQhsd/LDcH8wRFLpcqNYm88arUSuiJOwsDTji/VRi7tuYzki0j@pHcZAwpx7VXtiGha6eswHtjMKbnLZLGr4zUPj0G948lG@MN2Jp/q2zo@oEMnbdI7q2Tu@QeIRZHLCwsSMbiemdxtXOzs/Zo44hd4Hu54xqOd@baD@TD@CpKGAwHckGO4OPCx4RPCB8PPjZ8LLlSIz4sKpY3dEk49FjFoW1c4SgZwaruDUnUJx2fUpdTzQQiG0DCLoBYxbc73ZBJFPRZXlZuORHlqibksEJG/TtQv8HydxKS8KUSWUu@s@3oA7BlprtmC/izPMfmCxbAPIpLYyW8Z2tZinehn6ablpPBla6RX3qTxOW3aHwHvTGmlN6TR7Y09UkIhA85cYnXSimvIEtxWZ4MyXd@xopilTPaV5ri@Z76RFOlZUhMcd@@CB@8FsnFZePq5//0x9/98tX/OIZn@kZ399V/XX3@9avk7@rv/ubqk3//w2/g9vsv4JbCrj75DCA/@9erz3939ckv2P2zq5/9G5YZ/tufYlH8M@a09u3HmZqAvfrq91@8@iqp/uG3MxgZ3TfjXN9@gtTfgEimdlyMIPkYjPn865jg25@@@kaQQO0Pv0nL334MZSBk/2NFJgCIf8sUxnAO@wYb//nvXn316n//9MU//Dp7jgn1r68@/c@rT3919el/4JZZw61zXavgI19rVOJivpK512q1Ri1/cVmvwMXR@WJNg39NK1YqGl7FfIzg1ZoW44G0ptW0RiUP/PliLEBIqXFIsYL0gpmzMTRSQFSAZTVFUeM/VdTgeaGAXYraQBCW1bh@CeVK7ZJRXiBEqVxA7eLyAkF4qfEDJQF19h@RqToA1HmxAYUE2OAFJSMnK0nJcmeZUuXX6h7D1CchDe4A9RJvFxeXSnpNSeS1KfvAonqj3ohpwKp6Q9jaYG2qIxrdhncmGgHAATSMCmlVTs38XGMuR2sqyvj1F7KpzizhndBIa7zO/hjPuM6s4jonZoYqF0S7bFZlNb@5mRd/8W1zMwPMp4D0P0OclzfPNe2HI4lUR5ujqszPkjaVG2o1oD/ZxNSl6tCQtG6ANtl2ST8Kj0N/QZHlG3Lg@jQMjSPYMu3kwZb8CETJjkPPAuOuLGnaw9xzW3l8aq9Xt/Sd3gcrah0GUu2kfgK3Ex1u@kldh1ulhn@8zMDsEf@dnDR0BkI0Fk9OinojwHz56m//8Xj7ycPt3T/@32d/@uIXv7JPvR7FwtU/f7VVODPk9Xg76X4Q4GXgRZOrnymbdhDXTm1xndKp6/SlYdrZC2kMk32GURQNBfvpJAlcZ/wBiVrSBWm3Zbrq6suPr778/OrLv7/68udX/wL/v8T/L/9bfo2vRZCXjt0iPJ1ckkRaidn62k2pXXWMXssyiFtmZ0BuIee3kjMgyaq2cvjd2Ml5u42fXL6t5IrsrCy0vZyab@VSFC/niqce5K9t5UDF46UDyJnr/GSpkOMnIVDg35ZCIfsaDFTFoW@uoUpmFd928WkQeK1TZaOwt39wf/vx/l5Be7D9rPl0597jY4Q1H@w/aN7ff7J/v7Cs8nMZhbet2Fq7SV3UrJjFWJZiqXmz2HaioKuohVZuS4fGWpRRQauD0Lf7Sq6aU9XX82Tv8Fhz7DNKztfXSM927Z7hENqLHCPE150m3pWy2@wtouTFqqHnnwWkS31awJOroe04DIbnbeBeB8UXoB98PLAlragTcCFAa3k0cHNchJCA7zr1fa9ltJwRcfF0K/QIPQ@pawFH@j4UQ3Wp0@dnt5wCFYRdOyBGC1posNdSCsQIzkiPxm8/mdgTbhjgm0S4I4dHbyRO1gDocgFm14DxCumVFAdSMAokFmX8Cw/PCUSokb7hh7bhSBKzJHPEyGMM9JN2WZqDVnV8o0eqpB2HXY/2PH8EkPpDMKWxtHbr1uqagNZXbq2V4ZMHMxTBqzaAVpQlizpJWfJpx8b3NwIguMjdO8qVyfI57MgKJHd8L1PZfcYqy8sHBwVpLreHVdSNdEdpee9eXAai7ZiHSdjJsOzELJdS2zE6XPnuAQAPDCdAisNs5Xm2cpytHCWVS0nCYyXq@56v9IKOyjyH0d6W9x89OnxUJhcAvoRH0uYb/qWsSnPQQ0V6bodKSeVCOjRsYkc08eRTQUlYACOFhxMBdfRYo8Fe/2EkEAHYrLKwIwfJthmFGF74RQiec1lCSA4UT8gh@SopITSMfJfJmzBniGfGaI7jgTETVkpzXXsWVIhTAFupkHWV5InjSdKj/TvHGEDYS7x/sfvYfYfdoVt5T/FQ4J3bQL672/cPkPci7mOFC2H9oBbIPNm@D6hdjtodR@3ej8NH4epS1B6idjhqZxy1gygWaELXYz8Squ4i01GqKsHsIoYFsdCUYPYQs3cvVZRgdu5KIpBgMvScAfse3@@tM6/7vQKAO9DyMWRpDd2ME1Ngu0FouCZVkBRmEuQCNuCI3Vb3ew3W8WMw2mkkHSW0zLACFYFAVp7V0zvbx/vYpfW4B6G/CiSu7cW1ozHcURYXQzO0sQSMcpgGm3HMcvuP69waXSfr5D2y3mDmsaESw2ER5S7gECBizuJkVbLKXMSbzgSCgwokq0mawy9NkAzXLRC0DEVcOtGLMDljs5ELKVByOqrQr1NDMnIDGiZEKMCGBcCnZihGJjFME1ZCHKBCZb46ITS2ZRGMOcfvAyRpLtuo5cSWHlbXWDVu5cRwnmzsXNLchAN18aBAZEZPiZHFI5zbOhkXKmTS3MgpTYkiIwgoLEix2JU3SeVWXys1nrHWFQA1Pb8JTsWonRgfCQ7Yo75D@UihnQLp2p0uG2IxBSAsIzR4xMMYAIzK3Y2kWQ8wMgg5tmhl25fFvxejY6wQns7tQm@DK2HoOIhY97A4asu4FvOZHQMqjp0QxF@kQsrLK@dskcnawJ0UjDupwFB/tqs8x3qTp4IYUSAKa1m8JiCfcI2adV2GgdFzSt75jDSmnPYf2AG@sTuw6K0zZenyykW@U3jE06joprGB@L16Khn6mW6a7qKkXWytnRkcbL2dwoCHSsIgYBXm4Lf9QP6XC6PJ5VwE1Jhf3yWikkVqllszHQiCeQ@O@2USnY4u7p0pfGZ0zgwYaMsMDPMpYLu2aKkIqli8aGNcJTVQcrtdTgFaNVYr/BdjsvLAyDcLbM8Sea3QNPZTmYJQiIidNUYOVryFPubADvWbp6bZDLqQTyimBwsZpi6c05m1R2Dro5M4CMupb2x8XUPIKJMZu1Mgz6q2IdUrrTVXvT7bmAS@WYKYC8LZOyREAyZpJZ8GEKpy7MoEdmy9wRYFkYOymaAlfKxk99CgeCJiOQewsiSjjhlGI6tjnFclN5jdwJJwPOccGf5s@889n@8Mgb2A9kw2fJ21G@d5RtERJZW84GVgUcWk2IeMOx4l5bHU4PiI2cDdhTWVaLhEJ8M9S1iYHHGxeK8vto9ja2lGKFg6nd6gSFSOs9Z1@Hhwcpppw6fJV6Tp1VBEFORrbOzh26V@1A@vieEMHqN3hW24kjyOL0szyNh@CfNwLnZdyWYTqsgmUD6nQZ7lDTZbi1@MVEkuxzZMluWnfQLZBdssDvEVJiaMb99cOgQis@srTBkyqYyQ8/N0j28UGSlIX4CkpAVLwhlDCK1ACHiE8IyWg@P3hrKrtVhUch@4dg@2CnhgwX6/Fa6USPJ7G1hZsMzWlFxmRr@WWfgQ@JJKwiyxjovEz9xYUgiOtsqEn5uVxarE/dxJyhjDk0O8gKyry@XM6OKgW2@X9mKWtHkw@eYyaFo@v3WAv4SD5rSo4w1R6tp6KlUMvpkGrW2Up6Y7hri9lgqYnIqzEw4s/ZnZhAs1rXIa8ZhyxhWTp4bi0BEqZZLZgaXbOhx0quCy6DtzaSkXtnmaLfWEYEnIvf4blYgJRpUwM2PvORbiBI26UY/6BgxeTPBweLNfQ7KkJhM9SPrS7iu@4Xaogj1XgI5bg/s6JEn1rIcEn2h5XBMtSqrM4gbb3mSDtC4yGmYkOxjj53BKhojZDlPn2Ihm@FkTUuiPUEnXcC2HZcZj6lgFdoT40h2Mor@io30caJkRJ0fumYtfoGf4yny4QT3Z@wn5Ch69Hvp2x3YNhyRD1WA@bI3IVnrqCttE8d4d2os/pynCHtA8A1O66GX2vqyhl9Zu3755S7@5XtpYF@tF2z5vsrNnBTkh82CvjxeI41ZxngenSgSPVB033dTit7ZQh1lM03LgYAVPIDkjW7LUpRzJIR@KrGsrbL/nEph2If@MevwQlrLDWSyzd1RtdrQaUNyXQOjB3gLfb0QhyYwsy1hlYVcwx@NNKOemBVX@yqW2usLqyOEgPSoqizdfsElgtaPCFskuBxrjcep2I2FL52Sc2IP3Nm7lV1dUNEGsaeJXelOnuvGBLm9/5ji3GPQdWLVyJ26Oed8RDoJVddI3rEuynmG/y03dIvEWo1e2A7u8ni@XV/Llm7eXtF5hU5Yid2iwSR3wyyXDpPap1w8U9eKy3qjUCkUtL6NKEAojBH/7FvDpv019SoY68QDjc/VK/Fp7gWyL1@wX@a9FtQPHOFOlrtPHUFiEHmcGVq@JKWhyAH2bhk1OfEPSM/qKmGxMPKkjuTzIVOusj@OWNAqs@apaXyk33qwIdmiupYr3fhX@A0Te9zIkw8haL6/g9gTIUBqjFyCGBZiqvl5bLazdNtdWpUryVhQEDWW/4oxDAKZE/N0x9BdmWJDeqYS9@Gt5GS68TFLRSPcODfEXiKQ7icWJyiReewKOV@5Gjmi1WQq76gzyJhJ3@kQxy4EqaZqGb8V9V/NTQ0mtVkVxRaKgvP8H)

Next answer must not exceed 5474 bytes.

### Explanation

*Alice & Bob* is very similar to Brain-Flak, but instead of [left and right](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=45963981#45963981) stacks it has Alice's stack and Bob's queue. When Bob's queue is active loops (ie. `{code}`) get executed if zero is the top of the stack which is a good way to distinguish these.

I ended up with the following code:

```
<>
{   switch to bob who loops on zero; thus Brain-Flak won't execute but Alice & Bob will
 <> switch back to stack
 PUSH "bob & ecila"
 <>(()) switch to queue and push 1 to terminate loop
}
(()) push 1, st. Brain-Flak executes the loop, but Alice & Bob won't since we're on the queue
{
 {}  pop the 1
 PUSH "kalf-niarb"
 <>  switch stacks to terminate loop
}
<> switch to stack for both
```

[Try it with Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/##dZJNTsMwEIX3PsVb0UZqkbqmqlQWXCLywgkusWriENsKEPXsYezU1KUljuTJmz/lm6l6odpG1Mdp2u7YCMAOytUNnEFlKgyNgTamszAtvmVvnuAab/Ec8tYvWhwxmHbhID9l7Z1E5R32WtUSD3gOBZTWDNtdqltRr1DcOjJWEFqbQbVv@DI@yKJ2EBbqAOUWeRuGZXyKdNEpxtPVG5xFOkEoZ5OT8Svy2VhmdfJKyzw7T7o0/7f3laf8q/AicCCpyBh/eOklRPuKztsGm6A52b@rVhDMQJ6dWMyZ/SsC95jTP3O3NJY5fnU7gjggq1pSBrnoZZhlCI/N2cgwnoDOdFHcJNL3/3X@uiFHrEpe8hRDvEp@psgj7TK4yRH1WDoIlEExMSrEFnN03JcEKS6KvcvlslVpoXAwPe2ta6ZpWu9/AA) or [try it with Alice & Bob!](https://tio.run/##dZJNTsMwEIX3PsVb0UZqkbqmqkQXXCLywgkusWriENsKEPXsYezU1KUljuTJmz/lmxFa1XJdmWqatjs2ArCDcnUDZ0AqhsZAG9NZmBbfsjdPcI232PdCtesXLY4YTLtwkJ@y9k6i8g7PoSgesA8FlNYM212qW4n6GIpbR8YKQmszqPYNX8YHWdQOwkIdoNwib8OwjE@RLjrFeLp6g7NIJwjlbHIyfkU@G8usTl5pmWfnSZfm//a@8pR/FV4EDiQVGeMPL72EaF/RedtgEzQn@3fVCoIZyLMTizmzf0XgHnP6Z@6WxjLHr25HEAdkVUvKIBe9DLMM4bE5GxnGE9CZLoqbRPr@v85fN@SIVclLnmKIV8nPFHmkXQY3OaIeSweBMigmRoXYYo6O@5IgxUWxd7lctiotFA6mp711zTRNa/ED)

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6946 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M eliF MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 2d2b 5b2a  ODeerF$}++++-+[*
00000050: 2f2f 2f6f 7066 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a7a 667a  ///opfzzfzzfzzfz
00000060: 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a66 6666 7a66 667a  zzfzzfzfzfffzffz
00000070: 7a7a 7a7a 6666 7a66 7a7a 7a66 667a 667a  zzzzffzfzzzffzfz
00000080: 7a7a 667a 667a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a7a 7a66  zzfzfzfzzfzfzzzf
00000090: 7a66 7a66 7a7a 667a 667a 6666 667a 7a66  zfzfzzfzfzfffzzf
000000a0: 7a66 7a7a 7a66 7a66 6666 66e2 a086 e2a1  zfzzzfzffff.....
000000b0: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086  ................
000000c0: e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  ................
000000d0: a086 e2a1 865c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062  .....\. /+ #\. b
000000e0: 6173 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c  asename "$(readl
000000f0: 696e 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865  ink /proc/$$/exe
00000100: 2922 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720  )"|rev;:<<'EOF' 
00000110: 233e 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  #>>\.1+///      
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f              O\./
00000130: 2a20 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f  * .ggcGmiV.ZZ;oo
00000140: 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f  o"loG";?=0%S!11o
00000150: 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65  oo<"><>".#define
00000160: 2053 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a   S"C"       //A.
00000170: 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c  #ifdef __cpluspl
00000180: 7573 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020  us//l. f();     
00000190: 2020 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c         //i.#incl
000001a0: 7564 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23  ude<cstdio>//c.#
000001b0: 6465 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f  define S"++C" //
000001c0: 650a 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020  e. int///       
000001d0: 2020 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020    ".#endif//    
000001e0: 2020 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f     \..#ifdef __O
000001f0: 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322  BJC__.#define S"
00000200: 432d 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e  C-evitceJbO".#en
00000210: 6469 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e  dif. main(){prin
00000220: 7466 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69  tf(S)/*/main(){i
00000230: 6d70 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b  mport std.stdio;
00000240: 2244 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f  "D".write/**/;}/
00000250: 2a7d 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757  *}<.>  vwWWWWwWW
00000260: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000270: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000280: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757  wWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW
00000290: 7776 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777  wvwWWwWWWwvWwwww
000002a0: 7777 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757  wwwwwwwWWWwWWWWW
000002b0: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
000002c0: 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWwWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000300: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000320: 5757 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwwWWWWWWW
00000330: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWWWwww
00000340: 7777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wwwWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000350: 5757 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757  WWWWWWWWwwwwwWWW
00000360: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000370: 5757 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39  WWWwwwwwwwwwww.9
00000380: 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939  99 999 99.999 99
00000390: 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131  9 9.999v<>000011
000003a0: 3031 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67  0110.v  <>"efung
000003b0: 652d 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779  e-98",,,,,,,,,7y
000003c0: 332d 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020  3-v< @.>  #^Gv  
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040                 @
000003e0: 2c22 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020  ,"B"_"Tr",,@.   
000003f0: 763c 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933  v<[_"]Befunge-93
00000400: 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c  ">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
00000410: 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d  .   >#<"Befunge-
00000420: 3936 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020  96"> ^v$G001.v  
00000430: 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB
00000440: 2220 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  " _             
00000450: 2020 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c       v<.>  ,,,,,
00000460: 4023 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e  @#      ,"79-egn
00000470: 7566 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031  uferT"_v# $G0001
00000480: 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  <>.             
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004a0: 203c 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020   <>10000G$v.    
000004b0: 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c   #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,
000004c0: 2c40 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461  ,@#"79-egnuferda
000004d0: 7551 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020  uQ"_100000G$v.  
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237              ,,"7
00000500: 392d 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31  9-egnufetniuQ"_1
00000510: 3030 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c  000000G$!v@,,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,.        
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2020 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470      "79-egnufetp
00000560: 6553 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39  eS"_"Sexefunge-9
00000570: 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  7"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,
00000580: 4023 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  @#,.            
00000590: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005a0: 2020 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2026 2049 3820     <>"v"@. & I8 
000005b0: 4820 4920 2064 2020 2020 2020 2424 240a  H I  d      $$$.
000005c0: 6126 3867 2633 6734 6736 5239 5050 5050  a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPP
000005d0: 5050 3c0a 3e22 676e 616c 6f6b 6e69 4d22  PP<.>"gnalokniM"
000005e0: 4f4f 4f4f 4f4f 4f4f 4f2e 0a20 402c 2246  OOOOOOOOO.. @,"F
000005f0: 222c 2275 222c 226e 222c 2263 222c 2274  ","u","n","c","t
00000600: 222c 226f 222c 2269 222c 2264 223c 3e20  ","o","i","d"<> 
00000610: 7265 6420 646f 776e 2074 776f 2072 6564  red down two red
00000620: 206c 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77   left one yellow
00000630: 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079   up green down y
00000640: 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064  ellow up green d
00000650: 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074 6872 6565  own red up three
00000660: 2072 6564 2072 6967 6874 2074 776f 2079   red right two y
00000670: 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  ellow down yello
00000680: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
00000690: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
000006a0: 646f 776e 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  down one yellow 
000006b0: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067  down blue left g
000006c0: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 646f  reen down red do
000006d0: 776e 2074 776f 2072 6564 206c 6566 7420  wn two red left 
000006e0: 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 7965  one yellow up ye
000006f0: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c  llow down blue l
00000700: 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072  eft green down r
00000710: 6564 206c 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7265 6420  ed left one red 
00000720: 646f 776e 2074 6872 6565 2079 656c 6c6f  down three yello
00000730: 7720 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f  w down yellow do
00000740: 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265  wn blue left gre
00000750: 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074  en down red up t
00000760: 776f 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965  wo green down ye
00000770: 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  llow up yellow d
00000780: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 7265  own blue left re
00000790: 6420 7570 2074 6872 6565 2072 6564 2072  d up three red r
000007a0: 6967 6874 2074 776f 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  ight two yellow 
000007b0: 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  down yellow down
000007c0: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2030 3030 3131   blue left 00011
000007d0: 3130 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  1000010000010001
000007e0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030  0000010000010100
000007f0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000000000100
00000800: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100010000010001
00000810: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030  0000010000010100
00000820: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
00000830: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000100010000
00000840: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031  0000010001000001
00000850: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3030  0001000110000100
00000860: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100010000010001
00000870: 3130 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  1000010000010001
00000880: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031  0000010001000001
00000890: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0000010000010001
000008a0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031  0000010001000001
000008b0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000000000100
000008c0: 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100000100010001
000008d0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3130  0000000110000110
000008e0: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131  0000110000010011
000008f0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0000010001000100
00000900: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3130 3031  0100010000001001
00000910: 3130 3131 3130 3030 3030 3031 3130 3031  1011100000011001
00000920: 3131 3130 3030 3131 3030 3131 3030 3030  1110001100110000
00000930: 3030 3031 3030 3131 3130 3031 3131 3130  0001001110011110
00000940: 3030 3031 3130 3131 3130 3030 3030 3130  0001101110000010
00000950: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
00000960: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
00000970: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
00000980: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030 3031  0000001000110001
00000990: 3130 3131 3131 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  1011110001000100
000009a0: 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3031 3030  0100000100010100
000009b0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010000000100010
000009c0: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
000009d0: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
000009e0: 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000001000000010
000009f0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 300a 3031  0000000100110.01
00000a00: 2026 2026 2620 2626 2620 2020 2020 2620   & && &&&     & 
00000a10: 7b7d 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372  {}]........laocr
00000a20: 6168 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  ahC.............
00000a30: c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2  ................
00000a40: 86a8 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3  ................
00000a50: 9fe2 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690  ................
00000a60: e289 a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286  ................
00000a70: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2  ................
00000a80: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a90: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f  ................
00000aa0: c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692  ................
00000ab0: e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000ac0: 92e2 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000ad0: 86a8 c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82  ................
00000ae0: e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000af0: 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c  ................
00000b00: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2  ................
00000b10: 86a8 c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
00000b20: cf80 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2  ................
00000b30: 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2  ................
00000b40: a1ce b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000b50: e296 b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2  ................
00000b60: bbf0 9f98 ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f  .....Emotinomico
00000b70: 6ef0 9f98 b2e2 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 2b2d  n.............+-
00000b80: 2b5b 2d2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e  +[-++++[-<+++++>
00000b90: 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b  ]<[-<++++++<++++
00000ba0: 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3e 2b7b 7d5b  +<+++++>>>]>+{}[
00000bb0: 3c3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e  <<<<+++++++.>-.>
00000bc0: 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b  ---.<<-----.++++
00000bd0: 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e  ++++.-----.>--.>
00000be0: 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e2d 3e2d 5d3c 2b5b  ---.<+.>>->-]<+[
00000bf0: 3c3c 2b2e 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<+.<+++++++++++
00000c00: 2b2e 3e3e 2b2e 3c2b 2b2b 2e3c 2d2d 2e3e  +.>>+.<+++.<--.>
00000c10: 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2b 2b2b  +.--------.<++++
00000c20: 2e3e 2b2e 3e3e 7b7d 5d3e 5d3c 3e28 2829  .>+.>>{}]>]<>(()
00000c30: 2829 2829 2829 2829 293c 3e28 2829 2829  ()()()())<>(()()
00000c40: 293c 3e7b 287b 7d5b 2829 5d29 3c3e 287b  )<>{({}[()])<>({
00000c50: 287b 7d29 287b 7d5b 2829 5d29 7d7b 7d29  ({})({}[()])}{})
00000c60: 3c3e 7d3c 3e28 2829 7b5b 2829 5d28 3c7b  <>}<>((){[()](<{
00000c70: 7d3c 3e7b 7d7b 3c3e 2828 2828 2828 2928  }<>{}{<>(((((()(
00000c80: 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d  ((((()()()){}){}
00000c90: 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 2829 2828 2928  ){}){}){})()(()(
00000ca0: 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 295b 2829 2829  )()()()){})[()()
00000cb0: 2829 5d29 5b28 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d5d  ()])[(()()()){}]
00000cc0: 2928 2928 2929 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829  )()())((((((()()
00000cd0: 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 2828  ()()){}){}){})((
00000ce0: 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 295b 2828 2928 2928  )()()){})[(()()(
00000cf0: 2929 7b7d 5d29 2828 2828 2829 2828 2828  )){}])((((()((((
00000d00: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29  ()()()){}){}){})
00000d10: 7b7d 297b 7d29 2829 2828 2829 2829 2829  {}){})()((()()()
00000d20: 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2829 2828 2829 2829  ){}){})[()((()()
00000d30: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 5d29 3c3e 2828 2929  ()){}){}])<>(())
00000d40: 7d28 2829 297b 7b7d 2828 2828 2828 2828  }(()){{}((((((((
00000d50: 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b  ((()()()){}){}){
00000d60: 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829  }){}()){})((()()
00000d70: 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d  ()()){}){})[(([]
00000d80: 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28  []){}){}()])([](
00000d90: 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b  )){})[]())(([[][
00000da0: 5d28 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d  ]()]([]()((((([]
00000db0: 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d  [][])){}{})[]){}
00000dc0: 2929 295b 5d28 2929 3c3e 7d3c 3e3e 297d  )))[]())<>}<>>)}
00000dd0: 7b7d 297b 7b7d 283c 2828 2828 2828 2828  {}){{}(<((((((((
00000de0: 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29  ((((((()()()){})
00000df0: 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828  {}){}){}()){})((
00000e00: 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b  ()()()()){}){})[
00000e10: 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29  (([][]){}){}()])
00000e20: 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 5b5b  ([]()){})[]())[[
00000e30: 5d28 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d29 5b5b 5d28  ]()()()])[])[[](
00000e40: 2928 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d5b 5d5b 5d5b  )()()()])[][][][
00000e50: 2829 5d29 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829  ()])((((((()()()
00000e60: 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b  ){}()){}){}){})[
00000e70: 2829 2829 5d29 3e29 7d7b 7d28 7b20 2d7d  ()()])>)}{}({ -}
00000e80: 5f3d 2229 2b3b 3b2b 3b2b 3b2b 3b2b 3b3b  _=")+;;+;+;+;+;;
00000e90: 2b3b 2b3b 3b2b 3b3b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b 2b3b  +;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;
00000ea0: 2b3b 2b3b 2b3b 2b3b 3b3b 2b3b 3b2b 3b3b  +;+;+;+;;;+;;+;;
00000eb0: 2b3b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b 3b3b 2b3b 3b2b 3b2b  +;;+;;+;;;+;;+;+
00000ec0: 3b3b 2b3b 2b22 3b78 2d2d 3f79 0a20 3d79  ;;+;+";x--?y. =y
00000ed0: 3b79 3d22 7972 7275 4322 3b28 2129 3d73  ;y="yrruC";(!)=s
00000ee0: 6571 3b6d 6169 6e3d 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d  eq;main=let b!_=
00000ef0: 2222 696e 2070 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221  ""in putStr$(""!
00000f00: 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229  "snrettaPgnaB+")
00000f10: 2b2b 792d 2d3f 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 220a  ++y--?"lleksaH".
00000f20: 2d2d 4e27 5a69 2854 6a69 383d 402f 426d  --N'Zi(Tji8=@/Bm
00000f30: 5532 295b 2d5d 3c3e 5c5b 5c3c 3e5c 5c2f  U2)[-]<>\[\<>\\/
00000f40: 3c3e 5c2f 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e  <>\/\[/\/\<><><>
00000f50: 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 2f3c 3e5c 2f2f 5c2f 3c3e  \[/\/\/<>\//\/<>
00000f60: 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5c 5d2f 5c2f 2f5c  <><><><>\\]/\//\
00000f70: 2f2f 5c2f 5c5d 2f5c 2f5c 5c2e 2f5d 732a  //\/\]/\/\\./]s*
00000f80: 2f2f 2fe2 8899 5341 564e 4143 efbd 90f0  ///...SAVNAC....
00000f90: 9f92 ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e a140  ...ijome.......@
00000fa0: 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5573  ,ka"89-egnufenUs
00000fb0: 7373 7373 6161 6161 6165 6565 6565 6565  ssssaaaaaeeeeeee
00000fc0: 6565 6570 6165 6565 6565 6565 6565 6563  eeepaeeeeeeeeeec
00000fd0: 6973 6165 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 6969  isaeeeeeeejiiiii
00000fe0: 6969 696a 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  iiijeeeeeeeeeeee
00000ff0: 6565 6565 6565 6a7a 6163 6969 6969 6969  eeeeeejzaciiiiii
00001000: 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565 6561 6365 6561  iiiiiiijeeeaceea
00001010: 6365 7775 7575 7765 656a 6969 6969 6a69  cewuuuweejiiiiji
00001020: 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6161  iiiiiiiiiijeeeaa
00001030: 6161 6b65 6561 6161 6177 7677 3b2b 3b3b  aakeeaaaawvw;+;;
00001040: 2b3b 2b3b 3b3b 3b2b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b 3b2b  +;+;;;;+;+;;+;;+
00001050: 3b2b 3b3b 3b2b 3b3b 2b3b e2a0 80e2 a096  ;+;;;+;;+;......
00001060: e2a0 97e2 a08e e2a2 8ee2 a2a6 e2a2 a6e2  ................
00001070: a0ae 22                                  .."
```

Comment: I've always wondered: How do you generate hexdumps?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix: There are various tools available, for example [`hexdump`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUEppsLAIKYiLU1JoUYhI7UipTS34P9/AA "Bash – Try It Online") or [`xxd`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUEppsLAIKYiLU1JoUahoiLl/38A "Bash – Try It Online") (which is also the tool used to generate the ones posted here which you can see on the 3rd last line in the TIO links).

Comment: Only five more days...

Answer (score 4):

## 5. [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 136 bytes

```
void main(){//\
/*;ooo"><>"
printf("C")/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
J'zvSfN0cb&)}kf ;K-+ ,+;q,+;60d}[}q(-6+:puupd"*///⎚laocrahC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcMxDoIwFADQnVM0HRSK8JkcrGHBSRMXR11qK6ER@KUWTDS9ggfweF6k8pInG2ElijaECbUindB9nLwBLhEwjoi03JY0Mlb3ro5pRRNgoDuD1pGHU/lcI6c7mj@tdjdgDLgHFu2Xr@lUHwt5XST@XhN@yFKySvkwXxfKn/0QZ@t0Y8bRKMoA4Pf5tgKlFU0Vwh8)

Prints **laocrahC** in Charcoal, **C** in C, **><>** in ><>, **emmoS** in Somme, and **D** in D

Next answer cannot exceed **176** bytes (136 + 40).

### Explanation

`⎚` clears the canvas, `laocrahC` prints `laocrahC`

Answer (score 4):

## 11. Gol><>, 306 bytes

```
void /*hL!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X-@ PZh )X5  M!M elif MOC SODeerF$*/main(){//\
 /+\
1+///\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
>"Befunge-98";"Befunge-93";,,,,,,,,,,@
nq]j\m7-;l(e[KtR:R*///⎚laocrahC
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRnbVttI8hn9wrxUBEES2JYNCSEGMwHbJOxA4MRklgk4Hllq2Qq6eHUBM5nMJ@wH7Oftj2SruluybJzMnN3lHKC7637tantoJeOvX1fh0HHAAjayslFonUIa4W4S@Q8jP0ohZUkKYysOWZLA8AHeeqzzG/t0Gw2VVWhHvm9NEgZqO3KYClbogHoYj7KAhWmiQsLs1IvCBNwohiFLUxYDm05Y7LHQZopiWykcgI20Shpl9hgmsYeECrL2XHiIMrBIt5xhBQLrlkGSxYy0DCLHcx8AJdQmD5BEkI6RXzpmD0jCwAttP3OYgws6BN8LbxVmjyOohqCuNVQULWhLp1t06kQJnSqnh29fvz983R2cvO10r1oN5eiXy26vpa7p9zZU7X1S3FAVNwu5meBb4SizRkw3PisrnKe6CmvzXGqw1qjAGueE/kT3qsrK@fvLi/eXxHiIMUHWXBNkvdK9uui2L7sdggmOqPjvMbsjIProGg8EtQpPWrjJCVTo75HZobIiVemi4@0U/VHgVGCEEc7pCXHqpdBQVlxPWVkwHuXrC6ZsNgzSQnCvws2vktPNr@Ry7uCDPKJfKKbjNJ0kTdMceek4G9bsKDAv44eT9DzE2DAzjR@8NMrXjJmBlWDGmPexNcGcSZBD7mFQKS9VULlwvlZmMDRedQIHqnEW8uwqA3tREGCqqnGG2WxGk9RM6ET8rcXDRwQH@weIPnlIx1G4LShcLxnzP5R4i/htxOZYdjW1bXPohSb@X65MGyvLjiy/IJH7YrFMwM9egPh3XgDVhAMB17U0mMCB6bA7M8x8H7YO1huwvg5UYhJc5nE@/ES1eceqpO6I9JtCVBzagm81Kp9xEciyZi4clhkfMSyHEau@3M1tGhYn3BfucOhJk0g3Lkf0gNrQXcZoe4ER54JrQfo7pJbnU8lsbr9URSVjaV3CMWZQ57wH7fMzcD2fwel5@/D09JeSiEWUUphFCygb9jryl2TCKPJ5MiSxna9nIVN48rug3YT7k5gd8IZxoCk5B6pz6ow21Us0YaGuEYZm1GJmObrR5PS6Tc0wih3dNg5a21vUZMVuv7H1gnY2hFjHXqjtH6xrzMd@7Grrq58F0pc9rcJCp6VpWKy5QvsmV2XfJLVuwpvwgpdpk5Yaj4usW0mg3oTXWKqA7UEU6JP@9eXJeZ/w37Jpip0/ucfmHmR4W5AybGozajXYNHirO2hsb/8olhuNbbNRb4rN5rO6YYg@WCNmq6vwhk2dLJjQTlWmU4c78/cEuWmJ@dEE/DG1kmu5Is2iuVBLx1IzV1dnjhZt/uvXu8hzwNwYnz65qr6Ci4/jP/64evWq3oF6Rx1PxOGHMRhXzwHOnpwB89HzZ@dt6J13GIuP1zawJ3kh9nfTvFHA3LxRGpsmrc2NH3qB9/MPHz7sRVGk@tFrde/HVv1p70mjQQeUOsqqw1z0HfRUXHsu7mAwOD/6W3swKMGq7M5LbfZpeI5YGDnPlcbq2Fp6hrlhesEkilNIUqeGv160hx2vdh97KTM3Nsy9L@aGclAuxL1yMe1Vip9XSviP/qeb4EV1z9fZ9U/pu@a7DTTn3//8l29FdmyN21/dOArgN98bgpC6oUjpeFOxnWeK2/KtYOhYEDZ5BocVLR4WGaw4raFGd9rN1HXpV9t0da3Gqx2DohmbQ20OJPJfnvITEbv5M1GdmqHYLbxEMIeTBFuS/rLS6R6fHtLNVj07vBr8/ejkskdng7Pu2eC0@3P3tFI3hDd1oX9tuPMMZxGUqtu1nJfuGJt2zfWzZKwblaH2ykSDHMax0LIkjb2JrrU0w8DpCRtI1fdwLJnu7kDghV5g@cCCzLdSGnoWJibMJ5pFivHqPopvExizmFWouO49bN10Rh0BXegT@wr6OkadRzDMRolggrhOxJJQEywkB5qYJnE0tIb@A4RUgDgmYXliFiHFbKrioDHzJygwHUsMEpCOvQSsIVpo8ZGmAlZyCwHLZyibLknsCxBhR8JsxX/Bgyx@PAwFA7y8fJ9hvil5siQPicIzic9KUeQnMp1gYsWpZ/mKwjUpNUGRRygf3KayglaNYiuAFrh5agUsiLAlteD6LarS39h5/nx7R55ebz3faeLvJqqhS1qjj7hyrTjML9ZKzEYeTRoJInzWTi60JtSnjXq9AlrvpLRpX/FNvX58XFFWtA5tSTbhXczWnZN8jUiHJaSj8jon@KK4vjUSotvHeHhsYQdHjPPy5kN50ytvLooNzljUUlgcR7EeJCOD@41y3VW7796dv2vCZzz@gv8Ki5/EX1RDWcH41Gj40xuGYDJi6YDCMKDWrBMnWqCS0r8Fg2vyV7/Ph1GOgvEns5pSD41NmZ2llFxZKHqcI5lg/a4s8IHNFs2fMUuzOOT8FtS5p0uN1PEjVGZBS2Vl7C07lex0hO7vw64Bm@BHivKu@7pH6UMxEtGl4PG/R/wvBlVESiSCCG2f6N4cnh4T7ec8wrpgwuNgVAAfVacIagtQex7UPs2TRxfiZqAOgY4E6GgedEQgnmZS1mWcSVFviOhiJqqAtAnCU1hKKiAdgnROZoIKyNEbRSYStsLIv2MDfGfFwS73ehxU8HiEls8BGzvkZmpLiRcmqYWPO51QsY8QFZIhRe626zjo88DPnbFRvwiUlLJECxKEDPl6WaSPDntdCul1HkGMVwXyXSffXczBLsqw/LSEm3OgLMcmOMhzVujfuxbamCbswlPY7XP1eKnk53hNCheIE0TizhJoLdjmLhKmc4booAqUJeEjC9OA0OjWQkZ1XNLkSF7E1kxmExVhEOdZVZFfH5VkFiYsLZCIgYftP8aRXlYmWLaN9yAVqBS52Vpgmuuyjsrgtey6irJSNqpe6BLQdodvcysXynnR2JXC3IKCZImkIGBJToOj5RUudF3MCwPWpZKPJBWCrCRheB3lbLe@x1Vo/U2uecfa1fFoEMUDdCpl7UJ9FDAkzyY@E5XCRhUYe6MxL7EcAwGOlVoi47EGEGIIdxNq2QMcDVOOX1ll@8rwpzk4h0rms94u5faFEA7Ok4iHh@eRq9JNLDo7JVSeOymy/zxj0qxvTfklU9ZBOCmZd1KFg/5nV0W@8z1PJTmgAjq3LL8TiE66xii7rkTA8QWmCD5HzTEf@w/1QN94I7z0drmw2fUqWP6l9MjbqAzTXCH@V5EqSr8UpschKuzid@3S5OD37SMIeqghFUJSqQ6@WTEG/8c0WrzOZULN@fWvZFRxSS1zaymAyFhEcN4vi@BZdQnvPIKXqnNpwqAtSyDcpwgde9JSmVQ5e2ljvoUDFPLCbc4Oqq1crPRfDinzQyW/z9BdxvKbTGe5P@MpESWL3Flz6KjFn@DnFBTQePDJtgfJGF8Tuh3hRUYPF0HpL5sR@P3oFw6i9cw3Hn2sJHk0Ycl0iuhl0R4@9Bo7g@1owgeTJLYbmHNJunxCIjBCCitFG6BTQ0C3FqBz9w1ZlGQ@8eaMNujfVnmGRsELGSsokJQ/Mq7phdEvy5inNegzZEFSUHwQFCX6sv3TKBaTIZJXSJ9Fw3e53dTnOcZIrgz4KNZIYsimOMH3dl4lzbmnQe@C6yDcRTsDqnRFF@VeRqwsVlzOPprI8XHuLi0xRU0fP2@IJQmnrvUteF6cAuex4o/Rt5THt6HMKHyv8doLkSDOJuk3crgEp@zd4gNX8Y4T19ISND4v0StcsN3Vy68JQ74miL/AIZr6S96toyydZKSNpvGByXHiWUzwdcGHxfsxfdRKzMT4FrJ7RLLHsc6FEZHBEQW9eO6JQZGjIvc1fJQM8Uq45QApFRERTifiRSuO8w82y7e1vFS096EX4KhAH1fw74DSrQYU39TgzUJrfqdopY7@TWLpQ6QrNgWxwgOXya@6@KMQHe00QXwy1pS3kvDzqFhTDi@WeIVIt@vNUnWJo@d/zu3jMm6rqPKzOkqqT58f07dpaM6Q@dE9cd3ZnXGVxbdUoZ2XzUftjgNe7MwYLLbicsPBq7/UTQRT22nOMp6enPnGFk9D@bEibppQmsBmYx0VnSGpHPaXqaozKrL5MdnME5KkQI8m3xUiG4yh0MsMX1RsWskfaCzMAhZbWLz0wKPy5t@I8kdNKXsI9TdvosdWOGI6Ra6CgdvBv7v4SLoue0jSScvznbSo2HKN@3y8KSfptXzRcCX5x2LiUzi9hMR1x9Y5V9EcvqwhpfEDCRlboePzl/GcOL7BiZC@FcAq@ok9dKnQShWnZuFtGN2HZbqmKDfcF7Of5K8b/wE)

Next answer must not exceed 397 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4c21 582d 4020 505e  void /*hL!X-@ P^
00000010: 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030 4422 6870 2158  h~~X@@0D 0D"hp!X
00000020: 2d40 2050 5a68 2029 5835 2020 4d21 4d20  -@ PZh )X5  M!M 
00000030: 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053 4f44 6565 7246  elif MOC SODeerF
00000040: 242a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f  $*/main(){//\. /
00000050: 2b5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b53 6d69  +\.1+///\./*.Smi
00000060: 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d  V.ZZ;ooo"loG";?=
00000070: 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f22 3e3c 3e22 0a23  0%S!11ooo"><>".#
00000080: 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2222 0a23 6966 6465  define S"".#ifde
00000090: 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669  f __OBJC__.#defi
000000a0: 6e65 2053 222d 6576 6974 6365 6a62 4f22  ne S"-evitcejbO"
000000b0: 0a23 656e 6469 660a 7072 696e 7466 2822  .#endif.printf("
000000c0: 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374  C"S)/*/import st
000000d0: 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974  d.stdio;"D".writ
000000e0: 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a0a 3e22 4265 6675  e/**/;}/*.>"Befu
000000f0: 6e67 652d 3938 223b 2242 6566 756e 6765  nge-98";"Befunge
00000100: 2d39 3322 3b2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  -93";,,,,,,,,,,@
00000110: 0a6e 715d 6a5c 6d37 2d3b 6c28 655b 4b74  .nq]j\m7-;l(e[Kt
00000120: 523a 522a 2f2f 2fe2 8e9a 6c61 6f63 7261  R:R*///...laocra
00000130: 6843                                     hC
```

**NOTE:** the template file has been changed to run a different Befunge-93 interpretation that does not have problems with bounding box size.

### How??

I rearranged some code to avoid `0/0` in Befunge-93 (which will prompt for input), and added some code to distinguish ><> and  Gol><> by using the `S%` command(s). In Gol><>, both portions will be skipped as `S%` is one command, but in ><> it's `S` then `%`, so only `S` will be skipped, then modulo is used to get different results. The `/+ ... +/` are D-specific nesting comments.

Answer (score 4):

## 18. bash, 643 bytes

```
void /*hO!- #X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hs!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$++[*/main(){//\
 /+ #\
 echo hsab<<'EOF' #>>
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@
n*'um{ZKg,5kzy |Fa*///}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRrbctNI9jn6hXnpyAFJsWTZDgnBsT3kCuwASZEww@IYjyy1bBFdXLoQG8hU7Q/sB@wH7B/s81bNp8yPsOd0t2T5AkztbiB2d59rn2u3lKGVjL98qZBDxyEWoSMrG4XWc5JGMJtE/mzkRylJaZKSsRWHNEnIcEZeevTkI31/Ew2lCjmOfN@aJJTIx5FDZWKFDpEP41EW0DBNZJJQO/WiMCFuFJMhTVMaEzqd0NijoU0lybZS0iU20Ep@SIyEDdlHbeiSCjmibhaOqPFoR0qjzB6TSewBYwlEey6ZRRmxUPdcoE4C64aSJIsp7iKIHM@dEdCgNpmRJCLpGOSlYzoDEkq80PYzhzowwEXie@GNRO1xRIyQyFsNGVTjtKXVJq46UbK4uoOrSRQE1HC9KcKkySwdR@HO0urzw5dPXh8@OR08e3ly@qbTkI7@enV62ZG31FubGHYbt67JEuyaGY74VjjKrBFVtU/SBpMnV8jWIpca2WroZItxAg@Bw2RpYwi@BYZM426UpZMsFQzE5j7H9EMXfWGn1Ml5L68boS9tgKU3iR1MCGdDciC5f389AKgO0KKhtMH5/hJH4Uhg1chTOnWyYNIC6HTqkFw515M2lswDZlGXNlttaGAfoa5Brn/dUjGIOBPt@ld0JnNdN4@VO4yWcZpOkpZpjrx0nA1rdhSYV/HsWXoegtepmcYzL43yMaVmYCUQq@ZtbE0gWhPgkHuCyJgRMpGZCmwszWEnAHAChxhxFrI4LgMvMRQAIc4gj8xokposOPhnLR6uEHTbXUDPI4lRuF4yZh8Y0sv4x4DNsGwjtW1z6IUmfK9X5hhy2o4svyAR82KwTsDPXgD4H7ygyFUY11IIga7p0A9mmPk@aXbvNzA20C8CXOZxPnyPVeEDNVDdEeo3JVGxaHO@RlReYyKAZc1cWiwzLorFfr6nYbHCbOEOh97KluYlZomKkcCY6/OZpJbnY0ZVdx6V6c8gXE7OL8nx@Qviej4tOYyXiTLyk8hf49NR5DO3JrGdj9cZ/3VY3uBkxibEMJLU6Tzah0EmEL6@x4crlnloBKnrmfgBHPLFr3PY@w6HYnlvhccwtrzQzeybgkW@MB@tEF3F39l0Gn9l04yn4frWoryxBfKOcPTUEvKIcbhACKVT5l@CKaskLlGuw/Ykpl1WpbtKUeKxzGKDs7H4RBMaqgpiKFotppajai1Gr9rYs6LYUW2t29lpYq/ks3aj@RBnNgmh4Xqh0u7eV6gPbdVV7lc@caS7A0WnodNRFG2uUNtkqrRNVOs6vA4vWM1r4VBh3VUUQUEgX4c9qHvEg4rJqt1mv3f17LyP@C/pNIUGntxCjw4yaPqoDJ3aFCo91mHWX7qNnZ0f@XC7sWM26i0@qT6oaxpvPjVkVqnkZR5nsoSFHlX9nAA3JTHfmQR@TKVkWqZIq6jU2HmhbpmVytzQvBt/@fIh8hxibo/PNw1SeWM8Jhfvxr/99ubx4/oJqZ/I42STLb4dk@qbXSK/2HxBqA/Gf3F@TC7PTyiNz7aq1d42lHkvhNZqmtcSMaukAl@srI8Ta9huK6fnZwqpdLtSo2oijrn9w2hkPwm8n394@/YgiiLZj57IBz926vcuNxsNWGizmi1VHOqCdcmlDGPPhRkZDM6P/nI8GJRgBv3gpTZ9PzwHLPCt5wpzqFDJLzVz2/SCSRSnBIK9Br9edAANpnYbeyk1t7fNgztzu92WoKFcyQeVjwP5SNYfd5vVAwKnEfjp98iHg8rB/o3@cNY0Dh7rOmkDfreczZV3b@v1J5V3g60HRrdR7erFz2Mp3Fay4NPbn0b67s3HGfl8Zm2DGe76f/z9H7//@4@//cu3Iju2xse//7MKPz2jjV/Vbr@dD6vt0me3C5C2AFRrXQP@G0at3Tbwp1bNAXzaNXI4oHa76vxHw3/ap7viP5/lkALWU9Vev9fPcfoaTDmQfQMUwQBg64w1LgAF4DAsxNU49mP9xpL3Hxl0FGYuDV/LX9w4CshH3xsS7qRtSTgL6gbdeyC5Hd8Kho5FwhYrCaGuxMOiJEhOZ6hghbmeui7@KlVXVWrs5AtRrmjVoTIH8bFSex9BuLrqmYbV5gwqRY8XGl3hmQED3nNgUD53Kn1Nsjtw6IEykSTQQtVH@snp2fPDq9MT3Xhx@Gbwy9Gzq0tcG7w4fTF4fvrz6XO9rvFwVPmOasO9B3BqB3mqXct5qY5WtWuunyVjVdOHymMTtuhQhgV7TdLYm6hKR9E0uGdAmzR8Dw7o0/09EnihF1g@oUHmWyleD5buFpCveCovLiK3UXyTkDGNqY7169aDowauYdEFo/rIXgfrx6DziAyzUcKZAK4T0SRUOAvBAe8OkzgaWkN/RkKscXBhgAoIaQgU8/sFA42pPwGB6VhgoIB07CXEGsIOLXZU14mV3JCA5rcJG@0PpZdEUPQh3eErmIn6CoshZwCHLd@nkItSHj7JLJFYbLE7QBT5iQgwMrHi1LN8SWKalPoMjyyQT1w4VMOuRrEVkA5x82ALaBBB1e@Q3ktQpb@9t7u7sydWe83dvRb8VkENVdBqfcAVY8mhfjGWYjry8GScAMIn5dmF0iL1aaNe14ly@aw0OX7DJvX62ZkubSgnOEXZiHcxH588y8eAdJjTMA5HJZKjnOROgn4@4sKPz2DxzII2CRjn5cnb8uSyPLkoJnArwKpM4ziK1SAZacxyGO2ufPrq1fmrFvkEy3fwVex5M76TNWkDPFSjUy9VGxpnMqLpAB0xwP6nIiccgJLCwgWDHlqs32dXKoYCEYDbagk9FDqldpZieGUhbxOOYKKA4CU@pNohDVxNszhk/JbUucWTA6rjR6DMkpbSxthbtyrYqQBtt8m@RqrEjyTp1emTSwwg9BL3L7qPfR6xT3Ar9xQPBe7cPtI9PXx@hrSfch@rnAnzg6bDNf/wOYCOOeh4EXT8PA8flYubg04QdMRBR4ugIwSxQBOyruJMiHqKRBdzUQXkGCEsiIWkAnKCkJNnc0EF5OipJAIJimHkf6CDIHLiYJ9ZPQ50WB7BzheAjT00MxamxAuT1AptqiIqVBKkAjKgyM3Wi4M@c/zCGh31C0cJKWu0QEHAkI3Xefro8PIUXdrLPQj@0kk@O8lnFwuwizIsXy3h5hwwyqEMDvKY5fpf9rg2pkn2yT2y32fqsVTJ16F1chPwFUBixuJoHbLDTMS3zhiCgXRSliRt4NEZ0bBvAaM6DLFhohWhOOO2kQoxkPM8q9CuKymZhQlNCyRk4EEDiOESKjKTWLYNnRATVIisdpaY5rrcB2WgkbuuJG2UN1UvdAlwusem@S6X0nl5sxvFdgsKlMWDAoElOQ2Glmc413U5LjRyXyi5IqkQZCUJhYaUs21@iyvX@qtc84q1r8LSIIoHYFSM2qX8KGBAnk18yjOFjnQy9kZjlmI5BgAcK7V4xEMOAETj5kbUsgUYGoQca1rl/ZXh93JwDhXM57VdyO1zIQycBxFzD4sjV8ZezCs7BlQeOymw/zRn0qo3p6zJlHXgRkoWjaQz0P9sqsh3vmWpJAfoRGU7y3sC0gnTaGXTlQgYPsfkzmeoOeaq/UAPsI03gqa3z4TN2ytn@afCIy@jwk0LifhfeapI/ZKbVl1U7Iv12rXBwfrtCgQs1BAKAalQh0C5AvT/Xxgtt3MRUAt2/TMRVTSpdWYtORAYcw8u2mUZPM8ubp0VeCk71wYM7GUNhNkUoGNP7FQEVc5e7DGfwm25Pn3otuYLRicXK@yXQ8r8QMlvM3TXsfwq03nsz3kKRMEiN9YCOmjxHfycAh0aD97b9iAZw31CtSNoZHh14ZT@ujMC649@YSAcz23j4bNRwaNF1pxOAb0s2oOrXmNvsBNN2MEkie0GxFySrj8hIRggxS55GcBVjUObS9CFfoM7SjIfeTNG2/jVLJ@hQfBSxHIKIGWXjB7eMPplGYu0GtlkegNJQfGWU5Toy/ufRjE/GQK5jvosb3yf7RvrPMMYiZFG3vExkGiiKE7gxp1nSWvhanB5wXTg5sKZRgxs0UW6lxH15YzL2UcTcXxc6KUlpqDp6vUGWaJwrFpfg@fJyXFWFV9Fb0qr3VBEFNzXWO6FQBBnk/QrMVyCY/Q22YGruMfxtrQGjZ2X8B7O2e6r5duEJm4TyJ/jIE39EavW4o1YhygKOzA5Tjz3Cdwu2GHxduz5lDHjx7eQ3gKSPY5VJgyJNIbI6fl1jx8UGSpw34JLyRBawg0DCKmACHBc4Tdavpw/PS53a9FUlNehF8BRAR9YsPehabNBineQ0FlwzHqKUqroXyUWNgS6YlIQS8xxmXgtzC6FYGinRfjTspboStzOo2KMMbyc4jqS7tRbpeziS7vf5/ZuHbcKqPygDpLq090zfLMM2xlSP7pFrnv7c64i@dYqtPeotVLuGODh3pzBcikuFxxo/aVqwpnaTmse8XjlzCc2vxqKR40waZHSCWx@rMOk0wSVQ/80lTGnwj2vks0tIUgK9GjyTSGiwGgS3szgRkWnen5Bo2EW0NiC5MULHqY3@@sBdqkpRQ@ifvQmamyFI6qi53Rw3B587sMlqVe2kKATO89nYkfFlGncZ8ebcpD2xI2GKckejPHncGoJiekOpXMhoxl8XUFK4xkKGVuh47Ob8YI4NoETIb56gSz6ic5OMdFKGSdn4U0Y3YZluhZPN5gXZz/BX9W@LD8wLJ4V2vzynT8orCUTH@qhch1CquJzP4T3DCjXFaBIsoA/@KT8jxr4uzNPPMyk4Glo5fhSSUqtGDYNjOXDxGvtV1utZrX14OG2EegHslTURlnm3tftRbdzcnZE6PCXX8ZOk0eBj5gotyWOzLAnX4PziddKDIbs97w@x59XQyypyb1Hu9WdZv5Mm7@M56xkXfz5wH8A)

Next answer must not exceed 835 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a68 4f21 2d20 2358 2d40  void /*hO!- #X-@
00000010: 2050 5e68 7e7e 5840 4030 4420 3044 2268   P^h~~X@@0D 0D"h
00000020: 7321 582d 4020 505a 6820 2b58 3520 224d  s!X-@ PZh +X5 "M
00000030: 214d 2065 6c69 6620 4d4f 4320 534f 4465  !M elif MOC SODe
00000040: 6572 4624 2b2b 5b2a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b  erF$++[*/main(){
00000050: 2f2f 5c0a 202f 2b20 235c 0a20 6563 686f  //\. /+ #\. echo
00000060: 2068 7361 623c 3c27 454f 4627 2023 3e3e   hsab<<'EOF' #>>
00000070: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b67 6763 476d  .1+///\./*.ggcGm
00000080: 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f  iV.ZZ;ooo"loG";?
00000090: 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22  =0%S!11ooo<"><>"
000000a0: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2222 0a23 6966  .#define S"".#if
000000b0: 6465 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43 5f5f 0a23 6465  def __OBJC__.#de
000000c0: 6669 6e65 2053 222d 6576 6974 6365 6a62  fine S"-evitcejb
000000d0: 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a 7072 696e 7466  O".#endif.printf
000000e0: 2822 4322 5329 2f2a 2f69 6d70 6f72 7420  ("C"S)/*/import 
000000f0: 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772  std.stdio;"D".wr
00000100: 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a3c 3c0a 2022  ite/**/;}/*<<. "
00000110: 7254 223b 237a 5f22 4222 2c40 3e32 2b3b  rT";#z_"B",@>2+;
00000120: 2020 3e20 2020 205d 5b20 763b 233b 386b    >    ][ v;#;8k
00000130: 2c37 7932 2d3b 402c 2c20 3c3c 3c0a 3e22  ,7y2-;@,, <<<.>"
00000140: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 2223 5e5a 3030  Befunge-96"#^Z00
00000150: 4723 5e5f 2434 2d3e 312b 3e2c 2c2c 2c2c  G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,
00000160: 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 0a6e 2a27 756d 7b5a 4b67  ,,,,,@.n*'um{ZKg
00000170: 2c35 6b7a 7920 7c46 612a 2f2f 2f7d 5de2  ,5kzy |Fa*///}].
00000180: 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372 6168 43c2  .......laocrahC.
00000190: a62b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c  .++++[-<+++++>]<
000001a0: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c  [-<++++++<+++++<
000001b0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b  +++++>>>]<<<++++
000001c0: 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d  +++.>-.>---.<<--
000001d0: 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d  ---.++++++++.---
000001e0: 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e  --.>--.>---.<+.>
000001f0: 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829  >>((((((((((()()
00000200: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829  ()){}){}){}){}()
00000210: 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b  ){})((()()()()){
00000220: 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29  }){})[(([][]){})
00000230: 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b  {}()])([]()){})[
00000240: 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b  ]())(([[][]()]([
00000250: 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929  ]()((((([][][]))
00000260: 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28  {}{})[]){})))[](
00000270: 2929 402c 6b61 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665  ))@,ka"89-egnufe
00000280: 6e55 22                                  nU"
```

### Explanation

I added `- #` to the DOS code, which modifies a register just before it is overwritten. Similarly, the second line also got a `#`. This is necessary to make bash ignore the backslashes. Everything below is a heredoc that is ignored by `echo`. The two `<<` that introduce the heredoc needed to be balanced with `#>>` for Brain-flak.

Then, I noticed that Vim broke, so I changed the `S` (substitute line) to a `ggcG` (go to the top and change from here to the bottom).

Additionally, after fixing Somme some other small changes were necessary to make Brain-flak happy.

Comment: Why do you need the `ggc`?

Answer (score 4):

## 22. Haskell+BangPatterns, 814 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*/main(){//\
 /+ #\
 [ "$(basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)")" = "bash" ] && echo hsab || echo hsz<<'EOF' #>>
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@(
n4j\Ys`9)|bF4I*`p|*///]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLdtvIcmvhF@6mBWoMQAQIkrJliSJ5raetxLZ0LM9cX1M0BwSaJCw8GDwkyrLuOfmBLLLMIjnZZJVt1jnnfsp8Qf7AqeoHCD48M@cmtEV2dz27qrqqC@TQSSffvlXIoecRh9Cxk48j5zXJYphN4@B@HMQZyWiakYmTRDRNyfCevPXpyRf6@SYeKhVyHAeBM00pUY9jj6rEiTyiHibjPKRRlqokpW7mx1FKRnFChjTLaELobEoTn0YuVRTXyUiXuECrBBGxUjZkb7XhiFTIER3l0Zha@ztKFufuhEwTHxgrINofkfs4Jw7qLgWaJHRuKEnzhOIuwtjzR/cENKhN70kak2wC8rIJvQcSSvzIDXKPejDARRL40Y1C3UlMrIioWw0VVOO0pdUmrnpxuri6g6tpHIbUGvkzhCnT@2wSRztLq68P37788fDl6eD87cnph05DOfrz@9Orjrql37nEctu4dUNVYNfMcCRwonHujKluPCgbTJ5aIVuLXGpkq2GSLcYJPAQOU5WNIfgWGDKNu3GeTfNMMBCb@5rQ2y76ws2oJ3kvr1tRoGyApTeJG04JZ0MkkDx5sh4AVAdo0UjZ4Hz/lMTRWGDVyCs68/Jw2gLobOYRqdzIVzaWzANm0Zc2W20YYB@hrkWuf97SMYg4E@P6Z3Qmc11XxsojRssky6Zpy7bHfjbJhzU3Du33yf15dhGB16mdJfd@FssxpXbopBCr9l3iTCFaU@AgPUFUPBEqUZkKbKzMYScA8EKPWEkesTguA68wFAAhyeEc2fE0s1lw8PdaMlwh6La7gC4jiVGM/HTC3jCkl/GPAZthuVbmuvbQj2z4XK/MMZxpN3aCgkTMi8E6AT/5IeDf@mFxVmFcyyAEurZHb@0oDwLS7D5pYGygXwS4zONi@Bmzwi21UN0x6jcjcbHocr5WXF5jIoBlzV5aLDMuksWe3NOwWGG2GA2H/sqW5ilmiYqRwJjr85Vkjh/giaru7JfpzyBcTi6uyPHFGzLyA1pyGE8TZeSXcbDGp@M4YG5NE1eO1xn/x6i8wek9mxDLSjOvs78Hg1wgfH@Pz1cs89wKs5Fv4xtwkIvf57D7GxyK5d0VHsPE8aNR7t4ULOTCfLRC9D75jU1nyXc2zXhao8BZlDdxQN4Rjl45Qh6xDhcIIXWq/GOF6SsnvaFBwA4xsGKTFaQvjP7LGnIaxp/9ZfezRf6@zu1CZPUIVi4dLKFRuijf@lCGCQYKS38jol1H7WlCu6y0dLWiLmFtwKrsYsaMpzTSNcTQjFpCHU83Woxed7HQxomnu0a3s9PEAs9n7UbzOc5cEsEtwY@0dveJRgO4C4y0J5UHjvR4oJk08jqaBklbKtS2mSptG9W6jq6jS5aoWzjU2JVAZG5BoF5HPUjWxIc0z1L0Zr/3/vyij/hv6SyDW0d6BxeLMIebCipDZy6F8oTFgxXFbmNn5498uN3YsRv1Fp9Un9YNg1fMGjKrVGRtwpmqYHVCVb@mwE1L7U82gZetlUzLFGkV5QWvC@AYu1KZG5pfIb59u419j9jb1oNlkcrk3eYH6wW5/DT5y18@vHhRPyH1E3Vyyxc/Tkj1wzOivtl8Q2gA9n9zcUyuLk4oTc62Hqvw6m1DhfIjuBXY9rVC7CqpwEcPCrgOYUsjJ6Q4Rk/irYaAqWPX3tqy6QyuF4ZKOjLM@5hWWSmbpM6QfP0qJ1/abe304kwjlW5XaVRtFGRv/2E8dl@G/k9/@PjxII5jNYhfqgd/7NR/uNpsNGChzWqWUvHoCBxFrlQY@yOYkcHg4ujvjgeDEsyit37m0s/DC8CCMPFHwrI6VLIrw962/XAaJxmBw16DPz8@gAJbu0v8jNrb2/bBo73dbitwFt6rB5UvA/VINV90m9UDArcxePV75PagcrB3Yz6/b1oHL0yTtAG/W85mlU8f6/WXlU@DradWt1HtmsXrha5ETz9f/zn9ed/4Ojx7er798/TrNtih/8s//ctf//uXf/yvwIndxJkc//U/mE@sNn5Uu/22HFbbpfduFyBtAajWuhb8t6xau23hq1aVAD7tWhIOqN2uPn8Z@M94eCz@85mEFLCervf6vb7E6Rsw5UD2CVAEA4CtM9a4ABSAw7AQ1xDYD8R6HHQgdA70TaOT0n84wAD8GtCMDDcBoHbg/nWVJVu6qm6qaZTAZd@5hH7iqKoa1aoaBPQmdV6pEPxow//5t3/@T/9zHFIc/PKv//7CvHHUvX2LjqN8RKMf1W@jJA7Jl8AfEh4E24oIBgzw3afKqBM44dBzSNRi2SsytWRYZC/F6ww1jPDr2WiEf1p1pGs11lnAgdSM6lCbg/hYq32O4UyN9DMDE@MZJLUez4mmxg8xDHhNh0H5Xq/1DcXtwKUSMlqawhVF3zdPTs9eH74/PTGtN4cfBn86On9/hWuDN6dvBq9Pfzp9bdYNHu4631FtuPsUuiKQp7s1yUv3jKpbGwV5OtENc6i9sGGLHmVYsNc0S/yprnU0w4A@Dq4hVuBDAzTb2yWhH/mhExAa5oGTYfu11LtBXsGup2j07uLkJiUTmlATU@2dD5UF17A@gFEDZG@C9RPQeUyG@TjlTADXi2kaaZyF4IC9GSSdoTMM7kmE6RgaMkjWcMyBYt6/MdCEBlMQmE0EBgrIJn5KnCHs0GGtkEmg2pGQym7NRftDlSAx1CdIJ/AR3otSAIsRZwCXWYg8OOuKDJ/0PlVYbLEeK46DVAQYmTpJ5juBojBNSiWRRxbIJyNoWmBX48QJIYWOZLCFULyhQHVI7y2o0t/effZsZ1es9prPdlvwVwU1dEFr9AFXjBWPBsVYSejYx84jBYQH7fxSa5H6rFGvm0S7Oi9Njj@wSb1@dmYqG9oJTlE24l3OxyfncgxIh5KGcTgqkRxJkkcF7ktjLvz4DBbPHKjogHFRnnwsT67Kk8tiAl0XZn2aJHGih@nYYJbDaB@pp@/eXbxrkQdYfoSPYs@byaNqKBvgoRqd@ZneMDiTMc0G6IgBlmodOeEAlBQWLhj00GL9PmtZGQpEAG6rJfTQoPy5eYbhlUe8DHmCiQaCl/iQaoc0cDXLk4jxW1LnDi85qE4QgzJLWiobE3/dqmCnA7TdJnsGqZIgVpR3py@vMIDQS9y/6D72fsTewa3cUzwUuHP7SPfq8PUZ0j5IH@ucCfODYZIKOXwNoGMOOl4EHb@W4aNzcXPQCYKOOOhoEXSEIBZoQtb7JBeiXiHR5VxUATlGCAtiIamAnCDk5HwuqIAcvVJEIEEyjINbOghjLwn3mNWT0ITlMex8AdjYRTNjYkr9KM2cyKU6okImQSogAwpptl4S9pnjF9bouF84SkhZowUKAoZsvM7TR4dXp@jSnvQg@MskcnYiZ5cLsMsyTK6WcCUHjHJIgwMZs1z/qx7XxrbJHvmB7PWZeuyoyHUondwEfAWQmLE4WofsMBPxrTOGYCCTlCUpG3jLRzSsW8CoDkMsmGhFSM64baRCDOQ8P1Vo15UjmUcp3CGKbQADHwpAAk2@OJnEcV2ohHhAhchqZ4mp1OUJKAOFfDRSlI3ypuqFLiFOd9lU7nLpOC9vdqPYbkGBsnhQILAkp8HQ5Annui7HhUGeCCVXJBWCnDSlUJAk2@avceVaf5erzFh70AyMB3EyAKNi1C6djwIG5Pk0oPyk0LFJJv54wo6YxACA52QOj3g4AwAxuLkRtWwBhgYhx4pWeX9l@A8SLKGC@Ty3C7l9LoSBZRAx97A4GqlYi3lmx4CSsZMB@4c5k1a9OWNFpqwDN1K6aCSTgf7PpooD79cslUqASXS2M1kTkE6YxiibrkTA8Dkmdz5DlZir9gM9wDb@GIreHhM2L6@c5e8KD5lGhZsWDuLf5Kni6JfctOqiYl@s1q4NDlZvVyBgoYZQCEiFOgTSFaD//4XRcjkXAbVg198TUUWRWmfWkgOBMffgol2WwfPTxa2zAi@dzrUBA3tZA2E2BejEFzsVQSXZiz3KKXTj9dnzUWu@YHWkWGE/CSnzAyV/neFoHcvvMp3H/pynQBQspLEW0EGL38CXFOjQZPDZdQfpBPoJ3Y2hkGHrwimDdXcEVh@DwkA4ntvGx2fPgkeLrLmdAnpZtA@tXmN3sBNP2cUkTdwGxFyarb8hIRggxS55GsBVg0ObS9CFeoM7SvMAeTNG2/jRLN@hQfBSxHIKIGVNRg87jH5ZxiKtQTaZ3kBSUHzkFCX68v5nccJvhkBuoj7LG99j@8Y8zzDGYmSQT3wMJIZIilPouOUpaS20BleXTAduLpwZxMISXRz3MqK5fOIk@3gqro8LtbTEFDRdbW@QJQrHrPU9uDycHGdV8VX0prJaDUVEQb/Gzl4EBEk@zb4TwyU4Rm@TXbiKPo6XpTVo7L6EfThnu6eXuwlDdBPIn@MgTX2fZWvxjWOHaBq7MHleMvcJdBfssng38QPKmPHrW0TvAMmdJDoThkQGQ@T0vN3jF0WGCty3oCkZQkm4YQAhFRABjiu8o@XL8kF3uVqLoqL9GPkhXBXwgQX7vjlrNkjxHS9UFhyzmqKVMvp3iYUNga6YFMQKc1wuvnZnTSEY2msR/rSsJaoSt/O4GGMMLx9xE0l36q3S6eJLz36b26d13Cqg8tM6SKrPnp3hN/ewnSEN4jvkurs35yoO31qFdvdbK@mOAZ7vzhksp@JywoHSX8omnKnrteYRjy2nnLi8NRSPGmHSIqUb2Pxah4fOEFQe/d1U1pwK97xKNreEICnQ4@mvChEJxlCwM4OOis5M2aDRKA9p4sDhxQYPjzf7dQZrakrRg6hf/KmeONGY6ug5Exy3C@970CT1yhYSdGLnciZ2VEyZxn12vSkHaU90NExJ9mCMP4fTS0hMd0idCyeawdclpCy5RyETJ/IC1hkviGMTuBHit0Rwiv6e3p/iQSudODWPbqL4LirTtfhxg3lx9xP8dePb8gPD4lmhy5tv@aCwlk4DyIfadQRHFZ/7IbxnQbquAEWah/zBJ@U/GuHfTfriYSYFT0Mpx@@/lMxJYNP4Jc5h6rf2qq1Ws9p6@nzbCs0DVSlyo6py75vuots5ObsidPj3dNZOk0dBgJgotyWuzLCnwID7id9KLYYc9Pw@x59nQ0yp6Q/7z6o7TflMm//YgbNSTfHzjP8F)

Next answer must not exceed 1058 bytes.

### Explanation

Reuses the idea of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153892/48198): Defining a top-level operator `(!)=seq` which gets used in case of Haskell with BangPatterns enabled and otherwise the `let`-clause shadows that definition.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f6d  ODeerF$}++++[*/m
00000050: 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f 2b20 235c  ain(){//\. /+ #\
00000060: 0a20 5b20 2224 2862 6173 656e 616d 6520  . [ "$(basename 
00000070: 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20 2f70 726f  "$(readlink /pro
00000080: 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 2922 203d 2022  c/$$/exe)")" = "
00000090: 6261 7368 2220 5d20 2626 2065 6368 6f20  bash" ] && echo 
000000a0: 6873 6162 207c 7c20 6563 686f 2068 737a  hsab || echo hsz
000000b0: 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e0a 312b 2f2f  <<'EOF' #>>.1+//
000000c0: 2f5c 0a2f 2a1b 6767 6347 6d69 561b 5a5a  /\./*.ggcGmiV.ZZ
000000d0: 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d 3025 5321  ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!
000000e0: 3131 6f6f 6f3c 223e 3c3e 220a 2364 6566  11ooo<"><>".#def
000000f0: 696e 6520 5322 220a 2369 6664 6566 205f  ine S"".#ifdef _
00000100: 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  _OBJC__.#define 
00000110: 5322 2d65 7669 7463 656a 624f 220a 2365  S"-evitcejbO".#e
00000120: 6e64 6966 0a70 7269 6e74 6628 2243 2253  ndif.printf("C"S
00000130: 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274 2073 7464 2e73  )/*/import std.s
00000140: 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a  tdio;"D".write/*
00000150: 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 3c3c 0a20 2272 5422 3b23  */;}/*<<. "rT";#
00000160: 7a5f 2242 222c 403e 322b 3b20 203e 2020  z_"B",@>2+;  >  
00000170: 2020 5d5b 2076 3b23 3b38 6b2c 3779 322d    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-
00000180: 3b40 2c2c 203c 3c3c 0a3e 2242 6566 756e  ;@,, <<<.>"Befun
00000190: 6765 2d39 3622 235e 5a30 3047 235e 5f24  ge-96"#^Z00G#^_$
000001a0: 342d 3e31 2b3e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,
000001b0: 4028 0a6e 346a 5c59 7360 3929 7c62 4634  @(.n4j\Ys`9)|bF4
000001c0: 492a 6070 7c2a 2f2f 2f5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2  I*`p|*///]......
000001d0: 81b5 6c61 6f63 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b  ..laocrahC..++++
000001e0: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b  [-<+++++>]<[-<++
000001f0: 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  ++++<+++++<+++++
00000200: 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e  >>>]<<<+++++++.>
00000210: 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b  -.>---.<<-----.+
00000220: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d  +++++++.-----.>-
00000230: 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828  -.>---.<+.>>>(((
00000240: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d  (((((((()()()){}
00000250: 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928  ){}){}){}()){})(
00000260: 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29  (()()()()){}){})
00000270: 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d  [(([][]){}){}()]
00000280: 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928  )([]()){})[]())(
00000290: 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828  ([[][]()]([]()((
000002a0: 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29  ((([][][])){}{})
000002b0: 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20  []){})))[]())({ 
000002c0: 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b  -}_=")";(!)=seq;
000002d0: 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574 2062 215f 3d22 223d  main|let b!_=""=
000002e0: 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265  putStr$(""!"snre
000002f0: 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22 292b 2b22 6c6c  ttaPgnaB+")++"ll
00000300: 656b 7361 4822 2d2d 202a 2f2f 2ff0 9f92  eksaH"-- *///...
00000310: ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e a140 2c6b  .ijome.......@,k
00000320: 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522       a"89-egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 4):

## 28. Alice, 1024 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}
   @,,"rT",,,,,,,,,+1_;#:< v+;#!<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>5k$2+;>   [$v;#;8k,7y2-;@,,<<
>"Befunge-96"#^000G #^_$$3->,,,,,,,,,,@]
DT         .  .   *///{}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH(" {-
//+JAvY2a3*M;G0JeD-} -- )*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLcttIkmfhF@ZSAtkGIAIESdmyzNdYEiXbPbalsNQ9HlM0BwSKJCw8OHhIlNXqiPmB7Yg9bexhO/ayEbsxe9mIPW/EfIq/YP7Am1lVAMGH3R27Q1tkVeWzMrMys0COrHj6@XOJHDgOsQidWOkksF6SJITZLPRuJ16YkITGCZlaUUDjmIxuyWuX9j7SD1fhSCqRo9DzrFlMiXwUOlQmVuAQ@SCapD4NklgmMbUTNwxiMg4jMqJJQiNC5zMauTSwqSTZVkK6xAZayQuIEbMhe6uOxqREDuk4DSbUeLIrJWFqT8kscoGxBKLdMbkNU2Kh7plAnfjWFSVxGlHchR867viWgAbV2S2JQ5JMQV4ypbdAQokb2F7qUAcGuEg8N7iSqD0NiREQuVyXQTVOW1ht4KoTxsuru7gah75PjbE7R5g0u02mYbC7svry4PWz7w6eHQ9fvO4dv@3UpcM/XByfd@SyemMTw27j1jVZgl0zwxHPCiapNaGqdidtMXlyiZSXuVRJua6TMuMEHgKHyRnumzQI3GBC2GYeNKStEbgc5LCNdMM0maWJwBV7/iGi1110kZ1QJ2Ozum4EnrQFDtgmtj8jnA3JgOTBg80AoGqhoQNpi/P9fRSCbhyrSp7TuZP6syZA53OHZMqNXWlrxWpgLXXFBpW6puW7NsjlH8sqxhZnol3@EX3MjNDNQugeg2iaJLO4aZoTN5mmo6od@uZFdPsiOQ0gGKiZRLduEmZjSk3fiiGEzZvImkEQx8AhcxCR8aDIRGYqsLG0gPUA4PgOMaI0YOFdBJ5jhABClMLxMsNZYrKY4e/VaLRG0G13AT0LMEYxduMpe8NIX8U/AmyGZRuJbZsjNzDhc7MyR3DU7dDychIxzwebBHzv@oB/7fr5EYZxNYEQ6JoOvTaD1PNIo/ugjrGBfhHgIo/T0QdMFtfUQHUnqN@chPmizfkaYXGNiQCWVXNlscg4zyH72Z5G@QqzxXg0cte2tMg8K1SMBMZcnx9IYrkenqjK7pMi/QmES@/0nBydviJj16MFh/HsUUR@FnobfDoJPebWOLKz8SbjfxcUNzi7ZRNiGHHidJ7swyAVCF/e4@M1yzw2/GTsmvgGHLLFL3PY@wUO@fLeGo9RZLnBOLWvchbZwmK0RnQR/cKmk@gLm2Y8jbFnLcubWiDvEEfPLSGPGAdLhJA6Zf6xxvS5FV9Rz2OHGFixyRrSR0b/cQM59cMP7qr72SJ/3@R2IbJyCCtnFlbWIF6Wb7wtwtZPeqWCB61SwYNmw0d2wOzZbHGwxKRIeOyHiRuEvmuHASa8@SyMEvL6tHc8PDu4eN65lM00jkzPHZkBsBxCGU49Gl/KyBFX8v3lbJYm1Q/ryl4x211tsJ3D3eJscssiSn51hH8lcg48117O0xaumFBOaDSLKLwvsrXEysyYKJdBG2BdVtm7St4WYA3GpsjGyhTOaKAqiKFo1Yhajqo1Gb1qY58TRo5qa93ObgP7Kz5r1xuPcWaDRRPgobS7D8oK9aAXGysPSncc676l6DRwOooC1THTqG0yXdom6nUZXAZnrCI2caiwlkyUSEEgXwZ9qIrEhXrKauH2oH/x4nSA@K/pPIGuL76Bxs5PoVNEbejcptAHYJVmTUm3vrv7Wz7cqe@a9VqTTyoPa5rGO5YqMiuVsiYAZ7KEbQCq@kMM3JTYfG8SeJlKwbZMkWZex7FdgxNglkoLS/MW7vPn69B1iLlj3BkGKU3fbL81npKz99Mff3z79GmtR2o9eXrNF99NSeXtIyK/2n5FqAcOeHV6RM5Pe5RGJ@X7Crz6O6ZpXkrErJASfEBOoIHlQ4yUVXQfdpIEzBvaZrls0jm0dNg/tZrttnJ8eqKQUrd7KdUrwISsvU4vJXOH/GYysZ/57ve/efeuFYah7IXP5NZvO7VvzrfrdVhosy5AKjl0DB4h51jk@cs0D6SSOwYAGQ7tmZfG@GeankTGqtYqijJNF1B5G9y2IXe6Ydc07QLXSgX4miaVIMSSorogGgLLHedLl9WF1NPDb4@Gw6JyBr12E5t@GJ1mhBL06m4AfS13pnqumTumWHJ9llJAoSpTqgUNVPUmchNq7uyYrXtz514CkU91XY4uZD17VerDVqnZJteVVmm7LREEtkofh/KhrD/tProqNyqtLtD1y9etUmv/Sn982zBawKXdlrrFWlZ6X6vVnpHS@2G5vGt0cwH604HUu8htUGX/CcbC3f3g0z/881//59Of/9uzQjuypkd//TcWKUYbPyrdQTsbVtqF924XIG0BqFS7Bvw3jGq7beCrWskAfNo1Mjigdrvq4qXhP@3uPv/PZxkkh/VVtT/oDzKcgQZTDmSfAEUwANg6Y40LQAE4DAtxNYF9R4z7YUfW5Ja6rXVi@qcWevAHjyZktA0AuQPt93kSlVVZ3pbjAJJkYp3BLfOwImuVihu4iex59Cq2nqsyuTMk06x8e3D9h4a1u/Oq9az2Le0Z95CTiYZG/tvP//gX90PoUxx8@pd//dvP//SfxWIE8//69NN/fPrpL59@@ven@pUl7z8x6CRIxzT4Tv48jkKffISyRHh87UgizvD47j2Uxh3P8keORYImS8iBrkSjPCFLTmekYPG/nI/H@KdUxqpSZXdVSDGKVhkpCxAfK9UPIQT0WD3RMNefwCHq8zSvKzwtwYC3gzAo3hSVgSbZHbiPQI6OY@hu1Sd67/jk5cHFcU83Xh28Hf7@8MXFOa4NXx2/Gr48/v74pV7TeGpU@Y6qo72HcM8GeapdzXipjlaxq2NICVNV00fKUxO26FCGBXuNk8idqUpH0bTPJQIdrOG5cKWe7@8RH9zlWx6hfupZCV7oV54GQKbEe3T@6OAmjK5iMqUR1bF43LjQlOAaljwwqofsdbB@FOEddZROYs4EcJ2QxoHCWQgOeNuHlDqyRt4tCbDAwBUfyg9kE6BYPBFgoCn1ZiAwmQoMFJBM3ZhYI9ihxS7XOoFGifg0u//baH@oeySEkgtpCz78W1HcYDHgDOAeBBELiULKwie@jSUWW@zWHoZeLAKMzKwocS1PkpgmhSrPIwvkkzHcd2FXk8jySYeMs2DzoSGCktsh/degymBn79Gj3T2x2m882mvCXwXUUAWtNgBcMZYc6uVjKaITFy@tMSDcKS/OlCapzeu1mk6U8xeFydFbNqnVTk50aUvp4RRlI97ZYtx7kY0B6SCjYRwOCySHGcm9BK32hAs/OoHFEwt6FMA4LU7eFSfnxclZPoELO1YXGkVhpPrxRGOWw2gfy8dv3py@aZI7WL6Hj3zP29G9rElb4KEqnbuJWtc4kwlNhuiIITYfKnLCASgpLJwz6KPFBgP2tIOhQATgtppCDwWKu50mGF5pwMudI5goIHiFD6l0SB1XkzQKGL8VdW6wbUN1vBCUWdFS2pq6m1YFOxWg7TbZ10iFeKEkvTl@do4BhF7i/kX3sfdD9g5u5Z7iocCdO0C65wcvT5D2LvOxypkwP2g6KZGDlwA64qCjZdDRyyx8VC5uAeoh6JCDDpdBhwhigSZkXUSpEPUcic4WonLIEUJYEAtJOaSHkN6LhaAccvhcEoEEyTD0rtn1JPL3mdUjX4flCex8CVjfQzNjYordIE6swKYqokImQSogA4rMbP3IHzDHL63RySB3lJCyQQsUBAzZeJOnDw/Oj9Gl/cyD4C@dZLNeNjtbgp0VYdlqATfjgFEOaXCYxSzX/7zPtYE@b598Q/YHTD12VLJ1KJ3cBHwFkJixOFqH7DIT8a0zhmAgnRQlSVt4b0E0rFvAqAZDLJhoRUjOuG2kQgzkvDhVaNe1I5kGMfQf@TaAgQsFIKJ2Ik4msWwbKiEeUCGy0llhmunyAJSBQj4eS9JWcVO1XBcfp3tsmu1y5TivbnYr325OgbJ4UCCwIKfO0LITznVdjQuNPBBKrknKBVlxTKEgZWwbX@PKtf4i1yxj7cNVZzIMoyEYFaN25XzkMCBPZx7lJ4VOdDJ1J1N2xDIMADhWYvGIhzMAEI2bG1GLFmBoEHKsaBX3V4R/k4EzqGC@yO1C7oALYeAsiJh7WByNZazFPLNjQGWxkwD7uwWTZq0xZ0WmqAM3UrxsJJ2B/t@mCj3na5aKM4BOVLazrCYgnTCNVjRdgYDhc0zufIaaYa7bD/QA27gTKHr7TNiivHKWvyo8sjQq3LR0EP9PnsqPfsFN6y7K98Vq7cbgYPV2DQIWqguFgFSoQyBdAfrfL4xWy7kIqCW7/pqIyovUJrMWHAiMuQeX7bIKXpwubp01eOF0bgwY2MsGCLMpQKeu2KkIqoy92GM2JV0Q8njcXCwYnUyssF8GKfIDJb/OcLyJ5ReZLmJ/wVMgChaZsZbQQYtfwM8o0KHR8INtD@Mp3CdUuOM6Ll5dOKW3qUdg9dHLDYTjhW1c/NpC8GiSDd0poBdFu3DVq@8Nd8MZa0ziyK5DzMXJ5g4JwQDJd8nTAK5qHNpYgS7VG9xRnHrImzHawY9GsYcGwSsRyymAlF0y@njDGBRlLNNqZJvpDSQ5xTtOUaAv7n8eRrwzBHId9Vnd@D7bN@Z5hjERI42852Mg0URSnMGNOzslzaWrwfkZ04GbC2caMbBE58e9iKivnriMfTgT7eNSLS0wBU3XrzfIEoVj1voSPDucHGdd8XX0hrReDUVEwX2NnT18aB6ls@QLMVyAY/Q2WMOV3@N4WdqAxvolvIdztvtq8TahidsE8uc4SFN7wrK1@LK6QxSFNUyOEy18ArcL1izeTF2PMma8fQvoDSDZ00hlwpBIY4icnl/3eKPIUIF7GS4lIygJVwwgpAIiwHGF32j5cvbovlitRVFRvgtcH1oFfGDBfsGQNOok/9UAVBYcs5qiFDL6F4mFDYEun@TEEnNcKn7IwS6FYGinSfjTsqaoStzOk3yMMbx6xHUk3a01C6eLLz36ZW7vN3ErgcoPayCpNn90gr8Fge2MqBfeINe9/QVXcfg2KrT3pLmW7hjg8d6CwWoqLiYcKP2FbMKZ2k5zEfF45cwmNr8aikeNMGmSQge2aOvw0GmCyqG/mspYUOGe18kWlhAkOXo4@6oQkWA0CW9mcKOicz27oNEg9WlkweHFCx4eb/Z7H3apKUQPon50Z2pkBROqoud0cNwevO/DJalftJCgEzvPZmJH@ZRpPGDtTTFI@@JGw5RkD8b4czi1gMR0h9S5dKIZfFNCSqJbFDK1AsdjN@MlcWwCHSF@7wWn6Hf09hgPWuHEyWlwFYQ3QZGuyY8bzPPeT/BXtc@rDwzzZ4U2v3xnDwqr8cyDfKhcBnBU8bkfwvsGpOsSUMSpzx98Uv4zJP4VryseZlLwNJRy/EZPSqwINg2M5YPYbe5Xms1Gpfnw8Y7h6y1ZynOjLHPv6/ay2zk5axE6/JtHY7fBo8BDTJTbFC0z7MnToD9xm7HBkL2@O@D4i2yIKTX@5smjym4je6bNfyfDWcm6@GXP/wI)

Next answer must not exceed 1331 bytes.

### Explanation

Once I got **Alice** working (which nicely can reuse a lot of code) **Somme** was annoying, the code to fix it would have been `Sc+JAvY2a3*[;G>JeD` which breaks **Brain-Flak**. What I did, was to split the last line into two which gives us two unused lines to fix **Somme**<sup>1</sup>, this only required smallish fixes for **Brain-Flak**.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 0a20  write/**/;}/*}. 
000001d0: 2020 402c 2c22 7254 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c    @,,"rT",,,,,,,
000001e0: 2c2c 2b31 5f3b 233a 3c20 762b 3b23 213c  ,,+1_;#:< v+;#!<
000001f0: 0a20 2272 5422 3b23 7a5f 2242 222c 403e  . "rT";#z_"B",@>
00000200: 356b 2432 2b3b 3e20 2020 5b24 763b 233b  5k$2+;>   [$v;#;
00000210: 386b 2c37 7932 2d3b 402c 2c3c 3c0a 3e22  8k,7y2-;@,,<<.>"
00000220: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 2223 5e30 3030  Befunge-96"#^000
00000230: 4720 235e 5f24 2433 2d3e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  G #^_$$3->,,,,,,
00000240: 2c2c 2c2c 405d 0a44 5420 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,@].DT       
00000250: 2020 2e20 202e 2020 202a 2f2f 2f7b 7d5d    .  .   *///{}]
00000260: e28e 9ac2 bfe2 81b5 6c61 6f63 7261 6843  ........laocrahC
00000270: c2a6 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d  ..++++[-<+++++>]
00000280: 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  <[-<++++++<+++++
00000290: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b  <+++++>>>]<<<+++
000002a0: 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d  ++++.>-.>---.<<-
000002b0: 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d  ----.++++++++.--
000002c0: 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e  ---.>--.>---.<+.
000002d0: 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928  >>>((((((((((()(
000002e0: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28  )()){}){}){}){}(
000002f0: 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929  )){})((()()()())
00000300: 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d  {}){})[(([][]){}
00000310: 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29  ){}()])([]()){})
00000320: 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28  []())(([[][]()](
00000330: 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29  []()((((([][][])
00000340: 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d  ){}{})[]){})))[]
00000350: 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 2821  ())({ -}_=")";(!
00000360: 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574 2062  )=seq;main|let b
00000370: 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222  !_=""=putStr$(""
00000380: 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22  !"snrettaPgnaB+"
00000390: 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b 7361 4828  )++init"lleksaH(
000003a0: 2220 7b2d 0a2f 2f2b 4a41 7659 3261 332a  " {-.//+JAvY2a3*
000003b0: 4d3b 4730 4a65 442d 7d20 2d2d 2029 2a2f  M;G0JeD-} -- )*/
000003c0: 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2  //....ijome.....
000003d0: 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963  ......Emotinomic
000003e0: 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940  on.............@
000003f0: 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522  ,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

---

1: Alternatively I could have worked around by inserting the dots in an unused Alice section, like [this](https://tio.run/##rTrbcttIds/CL@xLC9QYgAgQJGXLMm9rXW3P2pbK0sx6TdFcEGiQsHDh4iJR1miq9gcyVXlK5SFTeUlVUpuXVOU5Vfsp/oL9A@ec7gYIXuyZSpa2yO4@1z59@lxAjqxk8vlzhew7DrEIHVvZOLRekjSC2TTyb8d@lJKUJimZWHFIk4SMbslrjx59pB@uopFUIYeR71vThBL5MHKoTKzQIfJ@PM4CGqaJTBJqp14UJsSNYjKiaUpjQmdTGns0tKkk2VZKesQGWskPiZGwIXurjVxSIQfUzcIxNZ7sSGmU2RMyjT1gLIFozyW3UUYs1D0XqJPAuqIkyWKKuwgix3NvCWhQm96SJCLpBOSlE3oLJJR4oe1nDnVggIvE98IridqTiBghkbcaMqjGaUurTVx1omRxdQdXkygIqOF6M4RJ09t0EoU7S6sv918/@27/2fHwxeuj47fdhnTwh4vj8668pd7YxLA7uHVNlmDXzHDEt8JxZo2pqt1JG0yeXCFbi1xqZKuhky3GCU4IDkzOcd9kYeiFY8I286ApbYzgyEEO20gvytJplgpcsecfYnrdwyOyU@rkbJbXjdCXNuAANokdTAlnQ3IgefBgPQCo2mjoUNrgfH8fR6Abx6qR53TmZMG0BdDZzCG5cq4nbSxZDaylLtmg2tC0YtcGufzjloq@xZlol3/EM2ZG6OUudI9ONEnTadIyzbGXTrJRzY4C8yK@fZGehuAM1EzjWy@N8jGlZmAl4MLmTWxNwYkT4JAfEJHxoshEZiqwsTSHHQHACRxixFnI3LsMPEcPAYQ4g@tlRtPUZD7D32vxaIWg1@kBeu5gjML1kgl7Q09fxj8EbIZlG6ltmyMvNOFzvTKHcNXtyPILEjEvBusEfO8FgH/tBcUVhnEtBRfomQ69NsPM90mz96CBvoHnIsBlHqejDxgsrqmB6o5RvxmJikWb8zWi8hoTASxr5tJimXERQ/byPY2KFWYLdzTyVrY0jzxLVIwExlyfH0hqeT7eqOrOkzL9CbjL0ek5OTx9RVzPp6UD49GjjPws8tec6Tjy2bEmsZ2P1xn/u7C8wektmxDDSFKn@2QPBplA@PIeH69Y5rERpK5n4htwyBe/zGH3FzgUy7srPEax5YVuZl8VLPKF@WiF6CL@hU2n8Rc2zXgarm8typtYIO8AR88tIY8Y@wuEEDpl/rHC9LmVXFHfZ5cYWLHJCtJHRv9xDTkNog/e8vGzRf6@7tiFyOoBrJxZmFnDZFG@8bYMW73p1SpetGoVL5oNH/kFs6fT@cUSkzLhcRClXhgFnh2FGPBm0yhOyevTo@Ph2f7F8@6lbGZJbPreyAyB5RDScObT5FJGjrhS7K9gszCpfVhV9orZ7mqN7Rx@LM66Y5l7ya/28K94zr7v2Ytx2sIVE9IJjacxhfd5tJZYmnGJchl2ANZjmb2nFGUB5mAsimzMTNGUhqqCGIpWi6nlqFqL0as21jlR7Ki21uvuNLG@4rNOo/kYZzZYNAUeSqf3YEuhPtRirvKgcsex7tuKTkOnqyiQHXONOibTpWOiXpfhZXjGMmILhworyUSKFATyZdiHrEg8yKcsF24O@hcvTgeI/5rOUqj6khso7IIMKkXUhs5sCnUAZmlWlPQaOzu/5cPtxo7ZqLf4pPqwrmm8Yqkhs0olLwJwJktYBqCqPyTATUnM9yaBl6mUbMsUaRV5HMs1uAFmpTK3NC/hPn@@jjyHmNvGnWGQyuTN5lvjKTl7P/nxx7dPn9aPSP1InlzzxXcTUn37iMivNl8R6sMBvDo9JOenR5TGJ1v3VXj1t03TvJSIWSUV@ICYQEMrAB/ZUvH4sJIkYN7INre2TDqDkg7rp3ar01GOT08UUun1LqVGFZiQldfppWRuk9@Mx/azwPv@N@/etaMokv3omdz@bbf@zflmowELHVYFSBWHunAi5ByTPH@Z5r5U8VwAkOHQnvpZgn@m6UvEVbV2WZRpeoDKy@CODbHTi3qmaZe4VqvA1zSpBC6WCnVr@B9Eg2N5brGDy9pc6unBt4fDYVk5g157qU0/jE5zQglqdS@EupYfpnqumdumWPICFlJAoRpTqg0FVO0m9lJqbm@b7Xtz@14CkU91XY4vZD1/VRvDdqXVIdfVdmWzIxEEtisfh/KBrD/tPbraalbbPaDrb123K@29K/3xbdNoA5dOR@qVc1nlfb1ef0Yq74dbWztGrxCgPx1I53b12/3rPzStne1X7Wf1b@kR@sLd/eDTP/zzX//n05//27ciO7Ymh3/9N@YpRgc/qr1BJx9WO6X3Xg8gHQGo1noG/DeMWqdj4KtWzQF82jNyOKD2eur8peE/7e6@@M9nOaSA9VW1P@gPcpyBBlMOZJ8ARTAA2DpjjQtAATgMC3E1gX1HjPthV9bktrqpdRP6pzae4A8@TcloEwByF8rv8zTeUmV5U05CCJKpdQZd5kFV1iD/@D69SqznMlxJtOLffv7Hv3gfooDi4NO//Ovffv6n/yxnG5j/16ef/uPTT3/59NO/P9WvLHnviUHHYebS8Dv5sxtHAfkIeYdwB9qWhCPh/dx9KLld3wpGjkXCFou4oa7EoyLiSk53pGB2v5y5Lv4pVVdVaqwZhRiiaNWRMgfxsVL7EIHHuuqJhsH8BG5Jn8dxXeFxBwa83oNBuRVUBppkd6HhgCCcJFC@qk/0o@OTl/sXx0e68Wr/7fD3By8uznFt@Or41fDl8ffHL/W6xmOfyndUG@0@hEYa5Kl2LeelOlrVrrlw5yeqpo@UpyZs0aEMC/aapLE3VZWuomnQ@kOJavge9MyzvV0SeKEXWD6hQeZbKXbsS@0@hEJslItnAzdRfJWQCY2pjtnhxoOqA9cwp4FRfWSvg/XjGJvQUTZOOBPAdSKahApnIThgOw8xc2SN/FsSYgaBHh7yC4QLoJi3/Aw0of4UBKYTgYEC0omXEGsEO7RY96wTqIRIQPMG30b7Q2IjEeRUiEvwEdyK7AWLIWcAjQ64JUQCKXef5DaRmG@xtjyK/EQ4GJlacepZviQxTUppnHsWyCcuNLSwq3FsBaRL3NzZAqh4IKd2Sf81qDLY3n30aGdXrPabj3Zb8FcFNVRBqw0AV4wlh/rFWIrp2MOuNAGEO@XFmdIi9VmjXteJcv6iNDl8yyb1@smJLm0oRzhF2Yh3Nh8fvcjHgLSf0zAOByWSg5zkXoJaesyFH57A4okFRQhgnJYn78qT8/LkrJhAR47pg8ZxFKtBMtaY5dDbXfn4zZvTNy1yB8v38FHseTO@lzVpA06oRmdeqjY0zmRM0yEexBCrCxU54QCUFBYuGPTRYoMBe5zBUMADcFstoYcC2dvOUnSvLOT5zBFMFBC8xIdUu6SBq2kWh4zfkjo3WJehOn4EyixpKW1MvHWrgp0K0E6H7GmkSvxIkt4cPztHB8JT4ueLx8feD9g7HCs/Ke4K/HAHSPd8/@UJ0t7lZ6xyJuwcNJ1UyP5LAB1y0OEi6PBl7j4qFzcHHSHogIMOFkEHCGKOJmRdxJkQ9RyJzuaiCsghQpgTC0kF5AghRy/mggrIwXNJOBIEw8i/Zv1HHOwxq8eBDstj2PkCsLGLZsbAlHhhklqhTVVEhUiCVEAGFLnZ@nEwYAe/sEbHg@KghJQ1WqAgYMjG6076YP/8GI@0n58gnJdO8tlRPjtbgJ2VYflqCTfngF4OYXCY@yzX/7zPtYFCbo98Q/YGTD12VfJ1SJ3cBHwFkJixOFqX7DAT8a0zhmAgnZQlSRvYmCAa5i1gVIchJky0IgRn3DZSIQZynt8qtOvKlczCBAqMYhvAwIMEEFM7FTeTWLYNmRAvqBBZ7S4xzXV5AMpAInddSdoob6pe6BLgdJdN810uXeflzW4U2y0oUBZ3CgSW5DQYWn7Dua7LfqGRB0LJFUmFICtJKCSknG3za1y51l/kmkesPehlxsMoHoJR0WuX7kcBA/Js6lN@U@hYJxNvPGFXLMcAgGOlFvd4uAMA0bi5EbVsAYYGLseSVnl/Zfg3OTiHCubz2C7kDrgQBs6diB0P8yNXxlzMIzs6VO47KbC/mzNp1ZszlmTKOnAjJYtG0hno/22qyHe@ZqkkB@hEZTvLcwLSCdNoZdOVCBg@x@SHz1BzzFX7gR5gG28MSW@PCZunV87yV7lHHkbFMS1cxP/TSRVXv3RMq0dU7Ivl2rXOwfLtCgQs1BAKAalQh0C4AvS/nxstp3PhUAt2/TUeVSSpdWYtHSAw5ie4aJdl8Px2ceuswEu3c63DwF7WQJhNATrxxE6FU@XsxR7zKemBkMdua75gdHOxwn45pMwPlPw6Q3cdyy8ynfv@nKdAFCxyYy2ggxa/gJ9T4IHGww@2PUwm0E@o0OM6HrYunNJfVyOw/OgXBsLx3DYefi8heLTImuoU0MuiPWj1GrvDnWjKCpMkthvgc0m6vkJCMECKXfIwgKsahzaXoAv5BneUZD7yZoy28aNZrqFB8JLHcgogZU1GHzuMQVnGIq1GNpneQFJQvOMUJfry/mdRzCtDINdRn@WN77F9Y5xnGGMx0sh7PgYSTQTFKXTc@S1pLbQG52dMB24unGnEwBRdXPcyor5843L20VSUjwu5tMQUNF1tb5AlCseo9SV4fjk5zqriq@hNaTUbCo@Cfo3dPXwqHmfT9As@XIKj9zZZwVX0cTwtrUFj9RL24ZztnlruJjTRTSB/joM09ScsWotvo7tEUVjB5Djx/Eygu2DF4s3E8yljxsu3kN4Akj2JVSYMiTSGyOl5u8cLRYYK3LegKRlBSrhiACEVEAGOK7yj5cv5s/lythZJRfku9AIoFfCBBfuJQtpskOJnAZBZcMxyilKK6F8kFjYEumJSEEvs4DLxSw3WFIKhnRbhT8taIitxO4@LMfrw8hXXkXSn3irdLr706Je5vV/HrQIqP6yDpPrs0Qn@2AO2M6J@dINcd/fmXMXlW6vQ7pPWSrhjgMe7cwbLobgccCD1l6IJZ2o7rbnHY8uZT2zeGopHjTBpkVIFNi/r8NJpgsqhv5rKmFPhnlfJ5pYQJAV6NP2qEBFgNAk7M@io6EzPGzQaZgGNLbi82ODh9WY/6GFNTcl7EPWjN1VjKxxTFU9Oh4Pbhfc9aJL6ZQsJOrHzfCZ2VEyZxgNW3pSdtC86GqYkezDGn8OpJSSmO4TOhRvN4OsCUhrfopCJFTo@64wXxLEJVIT4xRbcot/R22O8aKUbJ2fhVRjdhGW6Fr9uMC9qP8Ff1T4vPzAsnhXavPnOHxTWkqkP8VC5DOGq4nM/hPcNCNcVoEiygD/4pPx3Rvw7XE88zKRw0pDK8Ss7KbVi2DQwlvcTr7VXbbWa1dbDx9tGoLdlqYiNssxPX7cXj52TsxKhy79aNHaa3At8xES5LVEyw558DeoTr5UYDNnvewOOP4@GGFKTb548qu4082fa/IcwnJWsi5/u/C8)

Answer (score 4):

## 29. Quadrefunge-97, 1156 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#,,,,"79-egnuferdauQ"_v#!$G0001<>
      @,,,,,,,,,,,"79-egnuferT"<>
8X.          .   .*///{}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH(" {-
//28aZV8s&|?lz=a20-} -- )*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbcttKcs/CL@zLCNQRAJEgSMqWaYrksa62d21La/mcdUzRXBAYkrBw4eIiUZa1VfmBnKo8pfKQrbykKqnNS6rynKr9FH/B/oHTPRcQvNjn1Ca0Rc5MX6e7p7sH5NBOJl@@lMiB6xKb0LGdjUP7BUkjmE0j/3bsRylJaZKSiR2HNEnI8Ja88ujxR/rhKhoqJXIU@b49TShRjyKXqsQOXaIexOMsoGGaqCShTupFYUJGUUyGNE1pTOhsSmOPhg5VFMdOSZc4QKv4ITETNmRv1eGIlMghHWXhmJqPd5U0ypwJmcYeMFZAtDcit1FGbNRdCqyQwL6iJMliirsIItcb3RLQoDq9JUlE0gnISyf0Fkgo8ULHz1zqwgAXie@FVwp1JhExQ6Ju1VVQjdMWVhu46kbJ4uouriZREFBz5M0Qpkxv00kU7i6tvjh49fSHg6cng@evjk/edurK4d@9ObnoqFv6jUNMp41bN1QFds0MR3w7HGf2mOrGnbLB5KklsrXIpUq26hWyxTiBh8BhqsR9nYWhF44J28x2Q9kYgstBDttIN8rSaZYKXLHnTzG97qKLnJS6ks3yuhn6ygY4YJM4wZRwNkQCyfb2egBQ7aOhQ2WD8/1dHIFuHKtKntGZmwXTFkBnM5dI5UaesrFkNbCWvmSDct0w8l2b5PL3WzrGFmdiXP4efcyM0JUhdI9BNEnTadKyrLGXTrJh1YkC6018@zw9CyEYqJXGt14ayTGlVmAnEMLWTWxPIYgT4CAdRFQ8KCpRmQpsrMxhxwBwA5eYcRay8C4CLzBCACHO4HhZ0TS1WMzw92o8XCHotruALgOMUYy8ZMLeMNKX8Y8Am2E5Zuo41tALLfhcr8wRHHUnsv2cRMzzwToBP3oB4F97QX6EYVxNIQS6lkuvrTDzfdLobtcxNtAvAlzkcTb8gMnimpqo7hj1m5EoX3Q4XzMqrjERwLJqLS0WGec5pCn3NMxXmC1Gw6G3sqV55lmiYiQw5vp8Iqnt@XiiyruPi/SnEC7HZxfk6OwlGXk@LTiMZ48i8tPIX@PTceQztyaxI8frjP9DWNzg9JZNiGkmqdt53IRBJhC@vsdHK5Z5ZAbpyLPwDTjIxa9z2PsZDvny3gqPYWx74ShzrnIWcmE@WiF6E//MptP4K5tmPM2Rby/Km9gg7xBHz2whj5gHC4SQOlX@scL0mZ1cUd9nhxhYsckK0kdG/3ENOQ2iD96y@9kif1/ndiGyfAgr5zZW1jBZlG@@LcJWT3q5jAetXMaD5sCHPGDOdDo/WGJSJDwJotQLo8BzohAT3mwaxSl5dXZ8Mjg/ePOsc6laWRJbvje0QmA5gDKc@TS5VJEjruT7y9ksTKofVpW9Yra7WmM7l7vFXeeWeZT84gj/RuQc@J6zmKdtXLGgnNB4GlN4X5etf5vZ7t@ixx/mdIKnwkrXiGiXYRvkdVm30NXyVgPrOjZaDla7aEpDXUMMzajG1HZ1o8XodQd7pyh2dcfodnYb2LPxWbveeIQzB7yUAg@t3d3e0qgP/d1I2y7dcaz7fa1CQ7ejaVBxpUZti@nStlCvy/AyPGdVtoVDjbV5ouwKAvUy7EGlJR7UaFZfN/u9N8/P@oj/is5S6CSTG2gWgwy6T9SGzhwKvQVWftbodOu7u9/z4U5916rXWnxSflAzDN4FVZFZqSQbC5ypCrYWqOqnBLhpifXeIvCytIJtmSKtvDfAFhBOlVUqzS3N28IvX64jzyXWjnlnmqQ0eb351nxCzt9P/vjHt0@e1I5J7VidXPPFdxNSfvuQqC83XxLqgwNenh2Ri7NjSuPTrfsyvHo7lmVdKsQqkxJ8QJ6hoR1AAG3p6D7sTgmYN3KsrS2LzqBNxJ5sv9VuaydnpxopdbuXSr0MTMjK6@xSsXbIr8Zj52ng/fird@/2oyhS/eipuv99p/bdxWa9Dgtt1lkoJZeOwCPkAhsH/rKsA6XkjQBABgNn6mcJ/lmWr5CRbuwXRVmWB6i8tW47kI@9qGtZToFruQx8LYsqEGJpUV0QDYHljfKly@pc6tnhr48Gg6JyJr32Uod@GJ5JQgX6fy@EXpk7U78wrB1LLHkBS1OgUJUptQ9NWfUm9lJq7exY@/fWzr1yTQgYYF5ZKvL16HbXvG4rXUJK759er5j3SUU9VAeQboDiiQIL1@3eQO0XeohuzqrypI0Y3VK7WD275P311tNarY46MDT10WOTjsNsRA9VMlh1KVeHcywtEsSunf1WHVyXNpFlrd7uKlLP@auA/kYFjCbcI/IXDqsYj3f3/c//8M9/@Z/Pf//fvh05sT05@su/sWg12/hR7vbbclhuF967XYC0BaBc7Zrw3zSr7baJr2pZAvi0a0o4oHa7@vxl4D/j7j7/z2cSksN6ut7r9/oSp2/AlAPZJ0ARDAC2zljjAlAADsNCXENg3xHzftBRDXVf3zQ6Cf3DPkbRJ5@mZLgJALUD14qLNN7SVXVTTUJI/ql9Drfnw7JqlMte6KWq79OrxH6mq@TOVCyr0bTf/dhMtj9973/s2I2aeQ85nhho5L/@6R//7H2IAoqDz//yr3/90z/9Z7HIwvy/Pv/0H59/@vPnn/79SeXKVpvSd@EP6pdRHAXkI5RbwmN8RxGxjilk74Ey6vh2MHRtErZYUQgrWjzMi4LidoYaNjWXs9EI/7TySNeq7A4OaU4zykNtDuJjrfohgkM10k8NrDencJB7vNRUNJ4aYcDbXBgUb8Ba31CcDtyzoE4kCXTt@uPK8cnpi4M3J8cV8@XB28HvDp@/ucC1wcuTl4MXJz@evKjUDJ6edb6j6nDvAQ1Rnu5UJS/dNcpOdQRpaaIblaH2xIItupRhwV6TNPamutbRDONLiUBnbvreFSWz5h4JwF2B7RMaZL6d4oOKpacckK3x@UD@SOQmiq8SMqExrWABu/Gg2cI1LLtgVB/ZV8D6cYx372E2TjgTwHUjmoQaZyE44FMMSOtDe@jfkhCLXBpBuUshowHF/EkHA02oPwWB6URgoIB04iXEHsIObfbQoEKgASQBlc81HLQ/1F4SQdmH1Akfwa0osLAYcgZwv4OIhXSkyPBJbhOFxRZ7GhFFfiICjEztOPVsX1GYJoVOg0cWyCcjuMfDrsaxHZAOGclgC6DRg7LfIb1XoEp/Z@/hw909sdprPNxrwV8Z1NAFrdEHXDFWXOrnYyWmYw8v4wkg3GnPz7UWqc3qtVqFaBfPC5Ojt2xSq52eVpQN7RinKBvxzufj4@dyDEgHkoZxOCyQHEqSewWuEGMu/OgUFk9t6JMA46w4eVecXBQn5/nkXlGwwtE4jmI9SMYGsxxG@0g9ef367HWL3MHyPXzke96M71VD2QAPVenMS/W6wZmMaTpARwywAdKREw5ASWHhnEEPLdbvs6c4DAUiALfVEnpo0GA4WYrhlYW85LqCiQaCl/iQcofUcTXN4pDxW1LnBltHVMePQJklLZWNibduVbDTAdpuk6ZBysSPFOX1ydMLDCD0Evcvuo@9H7J3cCv3FA8F7tw@0j07eHGKtHfSxzpnwvxgVEiJHLwA0BEHHS2Cjl7I8NG5uDnoGEGHHHS4CDpEEAs0IetNnAlRz5DofC4qhxwhhAWxkJRDjhFy/HwuKIccPlNEIEEyjPxrdu2KgyazehxUYHkMO18A1vfQzJiYEi9MUjt0qI6okEmQCsiAQpqtFwd95viFNTru544SUtZogYKAIRuv8/ThwcUJurQnPQj@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@X7YrV2bXCwersCAQvVhUJAKtQhkK4A/f8vjJbLuQioBbv@kojKi9Q6sxYcCIy5Bxftsgyeny5unRV44XSuDRjYyxoIsylAJ57YqQgqyV7sUU5JF4Q8GrXmC2ZHihX2k5AiP1Dy2wxH61h@lek89uc8BaJgIY21gA5a/Ay@pECHxoMPjjNIJnCf0OGO63p4deGU/roegdVHPzcQjue28fDrGMGjRdZ0p4BeFO3BVa@@N9iNpqwxSWKnDjGXpOs7JAQDJN8lTwO4anBoYwm6UG9wR0nmI2/GaAc/GsUeGgQvRSynAFJ2yejhDaNflLFIa5BNpjeQ5BTvOEWBvrj/WRTzzhDIK6jP8sabbN@Y5xnGWIwM8p6PgcQQSXEKN255SloLV4OLc6YDNxfODGJiic6PexGxsnziJPtoKtrHhVpaYAqarl5vkCUKx6z1Nbg8nBxnVfFV9IayWg1FRMF9jZ09/DIgzqbpV2K4AMfobbCGK7/H8bK0Bo31S3gP52ybevE2YYjbBPLnOEhTe8yytfgSvkM0jTVMrhvPfQK3C9Ys3kw8nzJmvH0L6Q0gOZNYZ8KQyGCInJ5f93ijyFCB@xZcSoZQEq4YQEgFRIDjCr/R8mX59UGxWouiov0QegG0CvjAgv0yI23USf5rCKgsOGY1RStk9K8SCxsCXT7JiRXmuEz8QIVdCsHQbovwp2UtUZW4ncf5GGN4@YhXkHS31iqcLr708Oe5vV/HrQQqP6iBpNrs4Sn@xgW2M6R@dINc95pzruLwrVVo73FrJd0xwKO9OYPlVFxMOFD6C9mEM3Xc1jzi8copJw6/GopHjTBpkUIHNm/r8NAZgsqlv5jKnFPhnlfJ5pYQJDl6NP2mEJFgDAVvZnCjorOKvKDRMAtobMPhxQseHm/2OyZ2qSlED6J@9KZ6bIdjqqPnKuC4PXhvwiWpV7SQoBM7lzOxo3zKNO6z9qYYpD1xo2FKsgdj/DmcXkBiukPqXDjRDL4uIaXxLQqZ2KHrs5vxgjg2gY4Qv3uDU/QbenuCB61w4tQsvAqjm7BI1@LHDeZ57yf468aX5QeG@bNCh1@@5YPCajL1IR9qlyEcVXzuh/CeCem6BBRJFvAHn5T/vIp/de2Jh5kUPA2lHL9VVFI7hk0DY/Ug8VrNcqvVKLcePNoxg8q@quS5UVW59yvOots5OWsROvzbT3O3waPAR0yU2xItM@zJN6A/8VqJyZD9ntfn@PNsiCk1@e7xw/JuQz7T5r//4azUivjF0v8C)

Next answer must not exceed 1502 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 0a76  write/**/;}/*}.v
000001d0: 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938 222c    <>"efunge-98",
000001e0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c 0a3e  ,,,,,,,,7y3-v<.>
000001f0: 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020    #^Gv          
00000200: 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22 5472         @,"B"_"Tr
00000210: 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d 4265  ",,@.   v<[_"]Be
00000220: 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-93">,,,,,,
00000230: 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22 4265  ,,,,@<.   >#<"Be
00000240: 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624 4730  funge-96"> ^v$G0
00000250: 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65  01.v  ,,,,,"79-e
00000260: 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020 2020  gnufeB" _       
00000270: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20             v<.> 
00000280: 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c2c 2c2c 2237 392d   ,,,,,@#,,,,"79-
00000290: 6567 6e75 6665 7264 6175 5122 5f76 2321  egnuferdauQ"_v#!
000002a0: 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020 2040  $G0001<>.      @
000002b0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,,,"79-e
000002c0: 676e 7566 6572 5422 3c3e 0a38 582e 2020  gnuferT"<>.8X.  
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2e20 2020 2e2a 2f2f          .   .*//
000002e0: 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2 81b5 6c61 6f63  /{}]........laoc
000002f0: 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b  rahC..++++[-<+++
00000300: 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b  ++>]<[-<++++++<+
00000310: 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c  ++++<+++++>>>]<<
00000320: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d  <+++++++.>-.>---
00000330: 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  .<<-----.+++++++
00000340: 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d  +.-----.>--.>---
00000350: 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828 2828  .<+.>>>(((((((((
00000360: 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  (()()()){}){}){}
00000370: 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928  ){}()){})((()()(
00000380: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b  )()){}){})[(([][
00000390: 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829  ]){}){}()])([]()
000003a0: 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d  ){})[]())(([[][]
000003b0: 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b  ()]([]()((((([][
000003c0: 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29  ][])){}{})[]){})
000003d0: 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229  ))[]())({ -}_=")
000003e0: 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c  ";(!)=seq;main|l
000003f0: 6574 2062 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472  et b!_=""=putStr
00000400: 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e  $(""!"snrettaPgn
00000410: 6142 2b22 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b  aB+")++init"llek
00000420: 7361 4828 2220 7b2d 0a2f 2f32 3861 5a56  saH(" {-.//28aZV
00000430: 3873 267c 3f6c 7a3d 6132 302d 7d20 2d2d  8s&|?lz=a20-} --
00000440: 2029 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0   )*///....ijome.
00000450: 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e  ..........Emotin
00000460: 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac  omicon..........
00000470: e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  ...@,ka"89-egnuf
00000480: 656e 5522                                enU"
```

Thanks to @NieDzejkob and @BMO for help with fixing brainfuck, Alice, and BrainFlak in chat!

## Changes

I redid the funge section, and  applied  the fixes supplied  by @BMO for Alice, BrainFlak, and Brainfuck.

Answer (score 4):

## 31. Quintefunge-97, 1251 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_"Quintefunge-97"
.l        .       *///{}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//TJrf$8AlzKx5?x?I-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLcttIkmfhF@ZSAtUGIBIEKdmyRJFsvWXN2JbGUvd4TdEcECiSsPDg4CFRVmsi5gemI/a0sYed2MtG7MbsZSP2vBHzKf6C@QNvZj1A8GF3R@/SFllV@azMrMwskH07GX3@XCL7rktsQod2NgztlySNYDaO/PuhH6UkpUlKRnYc0iQh/Xvy2qNHH@mHm6ivlMhh5Pv2OKFEPYxcqhI7dIm6Hw@zgIZpopKEOqkXhQkZRDHp0zSlMaGTMY09GjpUURw7JW3iAK3ih8RM2JC9VfsDUiIHdJCFQ2rubCpplDkjMo49YKyAaG9A7qOM2Ki7FFghgX1DSZLFFHcRRK43uCegQXV8T5KIpCOQl47oPZBQ4oWOn7nUhQEuEt8LbxTqjCJihkRdq6ugGqctrG7gqhsls6ubuJpEQUDNgTdBmDK@T0dRuDm3@nL/9el3@6fHvbPXR8dvW3Xl4B@uji9b6pp@5xDTaeLWDVWBXTPDEd8Oh5k9pLrxoKwweWqJrM1yqZK1eoWsMU7gIXCYKnHfZGHohUPCNvNkQ1npg8tBDttIO8rScZYKXLHnH2J620YXOSl1JZv5dTP0lRVwwCpxgjHhbIgEkidPlgOAahcNHSornO/v4gh041hV8oJO3CwYNwA6mbhEKjfwlJU5q4G19DkblOuGke/aJNe/X9MxtjgT4/r36GNmhLYMoUcMolGajpOGZQ29dJT1q04UWFfx/Vl6HkIwUCuN7700kmNKrcBOIIStu9geQxAnwEE6iKh4UFSiMhXYWJnCjgDgBi4x4yxk4V0EXmKEAEKcwfGyonFqsZjh79W4v0DQbrYBXQYYoxh4yYi9YaTP4x8CNsNyzNRxrL4XWvC5XJlDOOpOZPs5iZjng2UCvvcCwL/1gvwIw7iaQgi0LZfeWmHm@2Sj/aSOsYF@EeAij/P@B0wWt9REdYeo34RE@aLD@ZpRcY2JAJZVa26xyDjPIdtyT/18hdli0O97C1uaZp45KkYCY67PDyS1PR9PVHlzp0h/AuFydH5JDs9fkYHn04LDePYoIp9G/hKfDiOfuTWJHTleZvzvwuIGx/dsQkwzSd3WzjYMMoHw5T0@X7DMczNIB56Fb8BBLn6Zw9ZPcMiXtxZ49GPbCweZc5OzkAvT0QLRVfwTm07jL2ya8TQHvj0rb2SDvAMcvbCFPGLuzxBC6lT5xwLTF3ZyQ32fHWJgxSYLSB8Z/ccl5DSIPnjz7meL/H2Z24XI8gGsXNhYWcNkVr75tghbPOnlMh60chkPmgMf8oA54/H0YIlJkfA4iFIvjALPiUJMeJNxFKfk9fnRce9i/@pF61q1siS2fK9vhcCyB2U482lyrSJHXMn3l7OZmVQ/LCp7w2x3s8R2LneLu8wt0yj52RH@lcjZ9z1nNk/buGJBOaHxOKbwvixb/zaz3V@ixx@mdAs8d3Ykn50dCyo8Te/xfYlsVO6XyM7pBE@Flc0B0a7DJuy1zTqVtpa3OdhTYJPnYKWNxjTUNcTQjGpMbVc3Goxed7Bvi2JXd4x2a3MD@0U@a9Y3nuPMgQhJgYfWbD9Z06gPveVAe1J64FiPu1qFhm5L06DaS42aFtOlaaFe1@F1eMEqfAOHGmsxRckXBOp12IEqTzzoD1htX@12rs7Ou4j/mk5S6GKTO2hUgww6X9SGThwKfQ12HazJatc3N7/lw/X6plWvNfik/LRmGLwDqyKzUkk2NThTFWxrUNUfEuCmJdZ7i8DL0gq2ZYo08r4E20840VapNLU0b0k/f76NPJdY6@aDaZLS6M3qW3OPXLwf/fGPb/f2akekdqSObvniuxEpv31G1Ferrwj1wQGvzg/J5fkRpfHJ2mMZXp11y7KuFWKVSQk@IMfR0A4ggNZ0dB92xgTMGznW2ppFJ9CiYj@422g2tePzE42U2u1rpV4GJmThdX6tWOvkV8Ohcxp43//q3bvdKIpUPzpVd79t1b65XK3XYaHJuhql5NIBBvIlNi38ZVn7SskbAID0es7YzxL8syxfIQPd2C2KsiwPUHlb33SgFnhR27KcAtdyGfhaFlUgxNKiuiAaAssb5EvX1anU84NfH/Z6ReVMeuulDv3QP5eECtw9vBD6dO5M/dKw1i2x5AUsRYJCVabULjSE1bvYS6m1vm7tPlrrj02lTcitsrOzQ/jfdIij22ZbuSUETDStexX5en6/ad4yBqX3p7cLDtirqAdqD5IhUOwpsHDb7PTUbqHDaeesKntNxGiXmsXa3ibvb9dOa7U66sDQ1Oc7Jh2G2YAeqKS36HSuDudY4ksFmvhK7d3CPQZY1uqwM/LVV7NdB7za6dotRyztVWZee6UCZ9fOfgubnUt8StWX3KriEyP@4bH76c///Lf/@fSn//btyInt0eHf/o2dB7OJH@V2tymH5Wbhvd0GSFMAytW2Cf9Ns9psmviqliWAT9umhANqu61PXwb@Mx4e8/98JiE5rKPrnW6nK3G6Bkw5kH0CFMEAYOuMNS4ABeAwLMQ1BPYDMR97LdVQd/VVo5XQP@xinP7g05T0VwGgtuDSdJnGa7qqrqpJCKUttS@GoX1QVo1y2Qu9VPV9epPYL3T1wVQs6@rX8WBte9//@JvJs28n356Zj6ZpoIX//pd//Kv3IQooDj79y7/@/S//9J/F/gHm//Xpx//49ONfP/3473uVG1vdlq4Mv1M/D@IoIB@hkyD8CK0r4ihhhtp6qgxavh30XZuEDVZzwooW9/Oao7itvob92vVkMMA/rTzQtSp7vABZVDPKfW0K4mOt@iGCMzvQTwwsZyeQJzq8klU0nnlhwDt4GBQv91rXUJwWXCGhDCUJXEj0ncrR8cnL/avjo4r5av9t73cHZ1eXuNZ7dfyq9/L4@@OXlZrBs7/Od1Ttbz2lIcrTnarkpbtG2akOIOuNdKPS1/Ys2KJLGRbsNUljb6xrLc0wPpcIXDpM37uhZLK9RQLwVWD7hAaZb6f4DGbuAQ4UA3z0kT/tuYvim4SMaEwrWB/vPOgjcQ2rOhjVR/YVsH4c42OFfjZMOBPAdSOahBpnITjgAxqoGn2779@TEGtoGkE1TSFhAsX0IQ4Djag/BoHpSGCggHTkJcTuww5t9jykQqC3JQGVj2wctD@UdhJBVwGZGT6Ce1G/YTHkDODqCuEKqUCR4ZPcJwqLLfagJYr8RAQYGdtx6tm@ojBNCo0MjyyQTwYNZQV2NYztgLTIQAZbAD0sdBUt0nkNqnTXt54929wSq52NZ1sN@CuDGrqgNbqAK8aKS/18rMR06OFzhgQQHrSzC61BahPIgRWiXZ4VJodv2aRWOzmpKCvaEU5RNuJdTMdHZ3IMSPuShnE4KJAcSJJHBW5HQy788AQWT2xowwDjvDh5V5xcFicX@eRRUbCA0jiOYj1IhgazHEb7QD1@8@b8TYM8wPIjfOR7Xo0fVUNZAQ9V6cRL9brBmQxp2kNH9LC/0pETDkBJYeGcQQct1u2yB1QMBSIAt9UQemjQvzhZiuGVhbyiu4KJBoLn@JByi9RxNc3ikPGbU@cOO1NUx49AmTktlZWRt2xVsNMB2mySbYOUiR8pypvj00sMIPQS9y@6j70fsHdwK/cUDwXu3C7Svdh/eYK0D9LHOmfC/GBUSInsvwTQIQcdzoIOX8rw0bm4KegIQQccdDALOkAQCzQh6yrOhKgXSHQxFZVDDhHCglhIyiFHCDk6mwrKIQcvFBFIkAwj/5bdKONgm1k9DiqwPISdzwDrW2hmTEyJFyapHTpUR1TIJEgFZEAhzdaJgy5z/MwaHXZzRwkpS7RAQcCQjZd5@mD/8hhd2pEeBH9ViJwdydnFDOyiCJOrBVzJAaMc0mBPxizX/7LDtYFWdpt8Q7a7TD12VOQ6lE5uAr4CSMxYHK1FNpmJ@NYZQzBQhRQlKSt4NUM0rFvAqAZDLJhoRUjOuG2kQgzkPD1VaNeFI5mFCTQf@TaAgQcFIKZOKk4msR0HKiEeUCGy3JpjKnV5AspAIR8MFGWluKlarkuA0y02lbucO87zm13Jt5tToCweFAgsyKkzNHnCua7zcWGQJ0LJBUm5IDtJKBQkyXbja1y51l/kKjPWNtzmhr0o7oFRMWrnzkcOA/Js7FN@UuiwQkbecMSOmMQAgGunNo94OAMAMbi5EbVoAYYGIceKVnF/Rfg3Eiyhgvk0twu5XS6EgWUQMfewOBqoWIt5ZseAkrGTAvuHKZNGbWPCikxRB26kZNZIFQb6P5sq8t2vWSqRgArR2c5kTUA6YRqjaLoCAcPnmNz5DFViLtoP9ADbeEMoettM2LS8cpY/KzxkGhVumjmIv8hT@dEvuGnRRfm@WK1dGhys3i5AwEJ1oRCQCnUIpCtA//8Lo/lyLgJqxq4/J6LyIrXMrAUHAmPuwVm7zIOnp4tbZwFeOJ1LAwb2sgTCbArQkSd2KoJKshd7lFPSBiHPB43pgtmSYoX9JKTID5T8OsPBMpZfZDqN/SlPgShYSGPNoIMWP4EvKdChce@D4/SSEdwndLjjuh5eXTilv6xHYPXRzw2E46ltPPymSfBokCXdKaAXRXtw1atv9TajMWtMktipQ8wl6fIOCcEAyXfJ0wCuGhy6MQedqTe4oyTzkTdjtI4fG8UeGgTPRSynAFJ2yejgDaNblDFLa5BVpjeQ5BTvOEWBvrj/SRTzzhDIK6jP/Ma32b4xzzOMoRgZ5D0fA4khkuIYbtzylDRmrgaXF0wHbi6cGcTEEp0f9yJiZf7ESfbRWLSPM7W0wBQ0XbzeIEsUjlnrS3B5ODnOouKL6BvKYjUUEQX3NXb28HuOOBunX4jhAhyjd4M1XPk9jpelJWisX8J7OGe7rRdvE4a4TSB/joM0tR2WrcXvC1pE01jD5Lrx1Cdwu2DN4t3I8yljxtu3kN4BkjOKdSYMiQyGyOn5dY83igwVuK/BpaQPJeGGAYRUQAQ4rvAbLV@W304Uq7UoKtp3oRdAq4APLNiPTtKNOsl/6AGVBcespmiFjP5FYmFDoMsnObHCHJeJ396wSyEY2m0Q/rSsIaoSt/MwH2MMzx/xCpJu1hqF08WXnv00t/fLuJVA5ac1kFSbPDvBn@/AdvrUj@6Q69b2lKs4fEsV2tppLKQ7Bni@NWUwn4qLCQdKfyGbcKaO25hGPF455cThV0PxqBEmDVLowKZtHR46Q1C59GdTmVMq3PMi2dQSgiRHj8ZfFSISjKHgzQxuVHRSkRc0GmYBjW04vHjBw@PNfqLFLjWF6EHUj95Yj@1wSHX0XAUctwXv23BJ6hQtJOjEzuVM7CifMo27rL0pBmlH3GiYkuzBGH8OpxeQmO6QOmdONIMvS0hpfI9CRnbo@uxmPCOOTaAjxK/24BT9ht4f40ErnDg1C2/C6C4s0jX4cYN53vsJ/rrxef6BYf6s0OGXb/mgsJqMfciH2nUIRxWf@yG8Y0K6LgFFkgX8wSflvxzj38p74mEmBU9DKccvLZXUjmHTwFjdT7zGdrnR2Cg3nj5fN4PKrqrkuVFVufcrzqzbOTlrEVr8y1Vzc4NHgY@YKLchWmbYk29Af@I1EpMh@x2vy/Gn2RBTavLNzrPy5oZ8ps1/2sRZqRXxY6z/BQ)

Next answer must not exceed 1626 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020  .>  #^Gv        
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22           @,"B"_"
00000230: 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d  Tr",,@.   v<[_"]
00000240: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c  Befunge-93">,,,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,,,@<.   >#<"
00000260: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
00000270: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
00000280: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
000002a0: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
000002b0: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
000002c0: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
000002f0: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000300: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000310: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 2251 7569  gnuferdauQ"_"Qui
00000320: 6e74 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722 0a2e 6c20  ntefunge-97"..l 
00000330: 2020 2020 2020 202e 2020 2020 2020 202a         .       *
00000340: 2f2f 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2 81b5 6c61  ///{}]........la
00000350: 6f63 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b  ocrahC..++++[-<+
00000360: 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  ++++>]<[-<++++++
00000370: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d  <+++++<+++++>>>]
00000380: 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d  <<<+++++++.>-.>-
00000390: 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b  --.<<-----.+++++
000003a0: 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d  +++.-----.>--.>-
000003b0: 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828  --.<+.>>>(((((((
000003c0: 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29  (((()()()){}){})
000003d0: 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928  {}){}()){})((()(
000003e0: 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b  )()()){}){})[(([
000003f0: 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d  ][]){}){}()])([]
00000400: 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d  ()){})[]())(([[]
00000410: 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b  []()]([]()((((([
00000420: 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b  ][][])){}{})[]){
00000430: 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d  })))[]())({ -}_=
00000440: 2229 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e  ")";(!)=seq;main
00000450: 7c6c 6574 2062 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453  |let b!_=""=putS
00000460: 7472 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150  tr$(""!"snrettaP
00000470: 676e 6142 2b22 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c  gnaB+")++init"ll
00000480: 656b 7361 4828 227b 2d0a 2f2f 544a 7266  eksaH("{-.//TJrf
00000490: 2438 416c 7a4b 7835 3f78 3f49 2d7d 2d2d  $8AlzKx5?x?I-}--
000004a0: 292a 2f2f 2ff0 9f92 ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f  )*///....ijome..
000004b0: 92ac e29e a1f0 9f98 ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f  .........Emotino
000004c0: 6d69 636f 6ef0 9f98 b2e2 8faa e28f ace2  micon...........
000004d0: 8fa9 402c 6b61 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665  ..@,ka"89-egnufe
000004e0: 6e55 22                                  nU"
```

## Explanation

Uses the relative get command, `G` with enough arguments to distinguish it from the other befunges.

Answer (score 4):

## 37. Grass, 2542 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left
.L           ..   *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-@^srEqRMM~dO-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbbttIls/mL8xLmXJHpCWKkp04tixpfLcz68Se2N3JxlY0FFmUGPOi5kW247jR2AEaGGCxPZiHxmIfttHA7mIvsw/TmH5YbD9l3jv/4B/Y@YPsOVW86eIk3TO0RVWde506VXUOxa4W9N@@LZB1wyAaoT0t6rnaPgk96A08@7JneyEJaRCSvua7NAhI95I8sujWS/rizOsKBbLp2bY2CCgRNz2DikRzDSKu@73IoW4YiCSgemh5bkBMzyddGobUJ/RiQH2LujoVBF0LSYvowCvYLlEC1mS3StckBbJBzcjtUWVlUQi9SO@TgW@BYAFUWya59CKioe2JwjJxtDNKgsinOArHMyzzkoAFlcElCTwS9kFf2KeXwEKJ5ep2ZFADGggktuWeCVTve0RxiThXE8E0zpuDLiDU8IJR6CJCA89xqGJaF4gTBpdh33MXR6EJx66vBUFdCH2i6AY5fzIkDeYExAvC/vqj3Y/Xd7c7Dx5tbT9t1oSNvz3ePmqKc9K5DgyMVBYFcA3zLrE1txdpPSrJV8IMUyEWyNyolAqZq5XJHJME0wizKia0jyPXtdweYSO@syDMdCEuQA8bbcuLwkEUxrSxY175dNjCedRDaiRixuGKawszMEuzRHcGhIshCZLcuTMdAVyrOBuuMMPlPvE9sI1TVcgevTAiZ1AH7MWFQRLjTEuYGfMaeEsa80GpJsvpqBVy@qs5CQOQC5FPf4WBwJzQSuLsGiOtH4aDoK6qPSvsR92K7jnqsX/5IDxwIWKoGvqXVuglbUpVRwsgztVzXxtApAcgIZkgIuJqEonITGBtIcNtAcJwDKL4kcvWQB55hGEEBH4Ea1D1BqHKAovfK353gqHVaAF5EoWMw7SCPrvhchin3wRqRqUroa6rXctV4Xu6MZuwH@ieZqcscT9tTFPwieUA/dBy0nUO7UoIIdBSDTpU3ci2yULrTg1jA@clRudlHHRf4I4ypAqa20P7LoiXAnUuV/HyMKYCRFbUMWBecLrRLCdj6qYQ5guz27UmhpRtT2NcjAXa3J5XJNQsG1dUaXElz78D4bJ1cEQ2Dx4S07JpbsL4FpMn3vXsKXPa82w2rYGvJ@1pzv/YzQ9wcMk6RFGC0GiuLEMjigluH@P9Cc/cV5zQtFS8gYQEeLuEpfdISMFLEzK6vma5ZqSfpSISQNaaYDr23zPo0L9l0EymYtraqL6@Bvo2sLWnxfqIsj7CCFunyL8mhO5pwRm1bbaIQRTrTBC9ZPwvp7BTx3thjU8/A/L7tGmPVZY2AHKo4fHrBqP6lad53ORKL5VwoZVKuNB0@EoWmD4YZAsr7uQZtx0vtFzPsXTPxQ3vYuD5IXl0sLXdOVw/3mueimoU@KptdVUXRHbgrI5sGpyKKBEh6fhSMSOdyotJY8@Y786m@M7g02JMm5YsSj44wt8ROeu2pY/u0xpCVDhOqD/wKdyn7da/jDTjp9jxacY3IXNlJZGzsqLCCU/DS7xP0Y3G/RTdKd@EzODS6XowcJJfuI7nevHZ1TXxU6EXnHXaEcCoWSoIVCNHIfR/vLVBwjVpK5zeNEgk8Z4aQlJJQ9WnNtUCGkMnT2U6CH@SLYPbHLeDSZ1nGYkwM@6njQkOlkuORFwPIfyexZrAUhqTFE/dBsRhi2WRrWKap2K@h1m6jlmQN6CuVESKolzxqWZIcp3xSzom3p5vSLrcai4uYMLPe43awn3s6bB6Q5BRbLTuzBWpDcWBWbxTuOJU16vFMnWNZrEImVhiUUNltjRUtOvUPXUPWfZVx2aR1QhxOhYziKfuCWRgxILcjeVds@2T4wcHbaR/RC9CKEOCc6g0nAhKF7SGXugUck7MCFkC3KotLv6cN@dri2qtWued0t2qLPPsuILCCoUk4cSeKGDKiaa@CkBaMVCfqwQutZjzLTOknuaMWD/AbqsWCpmneU3x9u0QZ1OdV64UhRT6j2efKmvk8Hn/s8@erq1Vt0h1S@wPOfBZn5Se3iPiw9mHhNowAQ8PNsnRwRal/s7cdQmuk3lVVU8FopZIAb7g/KGu5kB0zEk4fVjaEHCvp6tzcyqsBJnl6qv1RqO4fbBTJIVW61SolUAImbgOTgV1nvys19N3HeuTnz17tup5nmh7u@Lqz5vVj45mazUANFjGKRQMauImc4QJJb9UdV0oWCYgSKejD@wowI@q2gIxJXk1r0pVLSDldVlDh3Pa8lqqqueklkogV1WpACEW5s0F1RBYlpmCTiuZ1oONX2x2OnnjFDq0Qp2@6B4kjAIUj5YLNRSfTOlIVufVGGQ57PgCgyrMqFVI1ivnvhVSdX5eXb1W568bQouQ4fkTuNjtyTl2zn9848l5dqXCkq/0O98a7YzAb4F8IOjJ@TTgk9S2W1BPbkfxS1hZWSH8kzWxNWy0hCEhEEhZ5lZOrvuXi8qwQdbQ0YXnu8OJQF0rixtiBw504FkTADBsnHTEdi5Lb6XCytVXaw2kaRUa@Qy1RZ4P53ar1RrawQjF@ysK7bmRSTdE0plcHkM284x0rcBBOR7/WOwMoRoHkdUajI6882q0akBX3Z0bcsLCWnnkWivkJBta9Euxwxgyjluv/EBC18pYgXd2OKLnPZJGr5zUAT0C948cz6MDWCu8VzZM/VCEyYO53BHLYgQfFz46fEL4ePCx4GOIjRbxYRc2vHOXhOce69jUxCOBkktIbb1zEg1ID0osl1NNBSIbQMI@gFjHt3r9kEmM6fO8rN21I8pVjclhjZz6D6B@h@UfJCTlyySykfxo29EHYMtUd00X8Jd4Tqjs5@a8UoEbHmBX1@2bf/in//v@317/j615uq/1N1//181X375O/27@/u9uvvj3H/4Atz99DbcMdvPFbwHym3@5@er7my9@x@6/vfnNv2Kb4d/8GpvxP2POem8@z/Vi2Otv/vT162/S7g9/nMLI6L4b5XrzBVJ/ByKZ2lExMcnnYMxX3yYEb379@ruYBHo//CFrv/kc2kDI/keaTAAQ/5EpTOAc9h0O/qvvX3/z@n9ZaqA08KvUajeSZqmRu7dagGnEiFKlpcC/olQaDQWvSilB8G5LSfBA2mpJ2SXjn3x1nf7zXoJJcSeSdNI@aSc0bRm6HMm@AYtoQDA4E40A4AAaRoW0ckx9RZTrTlOUxVVpVm4G9NNVPLJf2TQk3VlAiM1BFB6F/pwkirNi4EIFFmqHPVfbKIlyqWS5VijaNj0LtD1JvFIEVd3bO1bWngf@9qePHz78zDhQrhVFxuj889e/@731wnMoNm7@@Zs/f/2P/50vc6H/7c2X/3nz5e9vvvyPtfKZJi4nW6P7sfjW9D2HvISCl/BsYl6IswpM1pbuCmbT1pyuoRG3ztJvt1z0u2n6LRjNbhEfK5xemCZ@iiVTKlZYfQQJZVEudYsZireLlRcepC@mtCNjZr8DKdMJT@rLRZ6EQoM/aIJG/kF1sS0LelP3HMjIg8DrvpBWylvbO/vrx9tbZeXh@tPOk40Hx0cI6zzcftjZ3/5ke79clXkiLPERVbpLd6mL@iS9ksiSDLmkV0xIAPuSXO4W11QYokEZFYw1CH1rIBWbRVl@WyBbB0eKbZ1RcrG8RByYK0ezCXUiWwvx94SxHyMgL8bH@OkvF@eefxaQPvVpGUuFcwuKS4RhgQNOtVF8Gbzv@/j0uxv1Ai4EaA2PBm6Ri4gl4I8NkEB3ta59SVwsJ0IPCosQckfgyH6QYKg@tQegMOzHFKgg7FsB0bowQo09ti8TLTgjDk1@ftDR/1DlEM9kOzp8OZdxKQNAlwvQ@xqEK5yuQhI@wWUgsNjiFaJnB3GAkYHmh5ZmCwKzJFfT8cgC/cSsCzMwKqgVHdIkZhJsDnU8KLCa5OQRmNKeX7p3b3Ephp4s3Fuqw6cEZkgxr9wG2rgtGNRO24JPexY@Dg@A4Kr44LBYJ9ULSDzKpHj0INfZfMo61erOTlmYKW5hF3Uj3WHW3nqQtIFoPeFhEjZyLBsJy7Vg2lqPK9/cAeCOBhUpUBzkO8/ynaN85zDtXAsC1hLU9z1fcoKezDyH0W6K248fHzyukysAX8NXOuZZ/1qUhRmYoQq9sEKpJnMhPRp2cCI6WGpKKAkbYGTs4VTACXqs3Wa/ozASiAAcVj22owi5lh6FGF6Ry4sbIxZSBMVjckipSWoIDSPfZfLGzDnHIh3NsT0wZsxKYaZvTYPG4iTANhpkWSYlYnuC8Hh79wgDCGeJzy9OH7tvsDtMK58pHgp8ctvIt7e@v4O8V8kcS1wImwe5TApkfR9Qmxy1OYra3E/CR@LqMtQWojY4amMUtYEoFmixrmM/ilXtIdNhpirFbCKGBXGsKcVsIWbrQaYoxWzsCXEgwWbo2UP24NN3lpnXfacM4B6MfARZW0I348YUWG4Qaq5OJSSFnQS5gA04Ered@E6bTfwIjPba6UTFWqZYgYpAIGtPm@mN9aNtnNKTZAZhvsok6W0lvcMR3GEel0BztIkEjHLYBjtJzHL7j064NVDVL5OPyHKbmceWSgKHo5O7gEOAiDmLkzXJInMRHzoTCA4qk7wmYQafUiEZnlsgqApNPDDRi7A547CRCylQcraq0K8TSzJyAxqmRCjAggPAp3oYr0yi6TqchLhAY5Wl5pjQxJY7YAwc5KYpCDP5QVVTWxzsLrFuMsqx5Tw@2Jl0uCkH6uJBgcicnhojS1Y4t3U8LmRyJzZyQlOqSAsCCgdSInbhXVK51bdKTXasZQlAHc/vgFMxasfWR4oD9mhgU75SaK9M@lCmsCWWUADC0EKNRzysAcDI3N1ImvcAI4OQY4dWfnx5/EcJOsHGwrO9Pdbb5koYOgkiNj0sjkwRz2K@s2NAJbETgvirTEi9unDBDpm8DdxJwaiTygz1F7vKs413eSpIEGUisZElZwLyxa6R867LMTB6Tsknn5EmlJP@AzvAN1YPDr1lpiw7XrnIDwqPZBuNp2lkIf6kmUqXfm6aJqcoHRc7a6cGBztvJzDgoVpsELDG5hDYroD8rxdG48d5HFAjfv2QiEoPqWluzU0gCOYzOOqXcXS2urh3JvC51Tk1YGAsUzDMp4DtW/FI46BKxMdjTLqkBUrum/UMoDQTtbH/EkxeHhj5boHmNJG3Cs1iP5MZE8YiEmeNkIMV76FPOHBC/c4LXe8EfagnJKhxDQtLF85pT8sR2Plopw7CduYbC1@IiGXUyZTsFMjzqi0o9WpLnUVvwBKTwNdrEHNBOD1DQjRg0lHybQChMscujGFHzhscURDZKJsJmsevhXwODYrHIpZzACsrMk6wwmjndYzyymSW2Q0sKcczzpHjz4//wvN5ZgjsZbRnfODLbNy4zzOKXtySyXPeBhY53hQHUHEnq6Q@UhocHTIbuLuwJxMFj@h0uecJy@MrLhHvDeL0ceQszQkFSyfLGxSJynHXug2fLE5OM2n4JPmCMHkaxhEF9Rpbe/hzvB8NwltiOIfH6F1gCVdax/FjaQoZy5ewDudil6V8NSHH1QTK5zTIU11hu3X8GlyTFIssYTIMP5sTqC5Ysnjet2zKhPH0zaXnQKT3fYkpQyaZEXJ@Xu7xRJGRgvQ5KEq6cCScMUSsFQgBjxBe0XJw8kNt/rSOD5Xix67lQKqADyzYC5ThQo2k7yPCyYJtdqYUczv6rcyxD4Ev7aTMApu4KH6PlBWF4GijTvjTsnp8KnE/99I2xvD4Ei8j62K1nltdHHTv/dKeT5NWAJPvVkFT9eLeDr6KCsPpUts7R6lLy5nUePFNNWhppT6x3THE/aVMwPhWnN9w4OjP7SZcqG7Us4jHkjPp6Lw0jB81QqdOchlYltbhopNjLoN@MJeSceGYJ9kyT8QsKbk3eKeSeIORBazMoKKiF@WkQKNu5FBfg8WLBR4ub/a6MStqctGDpC@tgeRrbo9KOHNlmLgluC9DkXSS91DMF4886cUjSrvM4jZLb/JBehJXNMxI9mCMP4eTckTMdtg6R1Y0w0/bkEL/EpX0NdewWWU8oo51ICPEtxxgFf0NvdzGhZZbcWLknrn4A0yOr86XG/TT3C@WL8lvxx8Yps8KdV58Jw8KK8HAhv2weOrCUsXnfog/UWC7LgBHEDn8wSflb0HzV32s@GEmhZmGoxzf3xD42zYgWFwPrPpyqV5fKNXv3p9XnPKqKKR7oyjy2S/ro9PO2VmK0OTvmSiLCzwKbKREvfU4ZYYx2TLkJ1Y9UBixfWK1OX22G@KWGny0cq@0uJA80@Zv4HJRYjl@Z/j/AQ)

Next answer must not exceed 3304 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5777  >  vwWWWWwWWWWWw
000001e0: 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757  vwWWwWWWwvwWWwWW
000001f0: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
00000200: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000210: 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777 7777  WwWWWwvWwwwwwwww
00000220: 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777 5757  wwwWWWwWWWWWWwWW
00000230: 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777  WWWWWwWWWWWWWWWw
00000240: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWwWWW
00000250: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
00000260: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWwWWW
00000280: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWw
00000290: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwwWWWWWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777 7757  WWWWWWWWWwwwwwwW
000002c0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWwwwwwWWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWw
000002f0: 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939 2039  wwwwwwwwww.999 9
00000300: 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a  99 99.999 999 9.
00000310: 3939 3976 3c3e 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675  999v<>.v  <>"efu
00000320: 6e67 652d 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  nge-98",,,,,,,,,
00000330: 3779 332d 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776  7y3-v< @.>  #^Gv
00000340: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000350: 2040 2c22 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20   @,"B"_"Tr",,@. 
00000360: 2020 763c 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d    v<[_"]Befunge-
00000370: 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c  93">,,,,,,,,,,0|
00000380: 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67  @<.   >#<"Befung
00000390: 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76  e-96"> ^v$G001.v
000003a0: 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566    ,,,,,"79-egnuf
000003b0: 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  eB" _           
000003c0: 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c         v<.>  ,,,
000003d0: 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65  ,,@#      ,"79-e
000003e0: 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030  gnuferT"_v# $G00
000003f0: 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  01<>.           
00000400: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000410: 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020     <>10000G$v.  
00000420: 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c     #@,,,,,,,,,,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572  ,,,@#"79-egnufer
00000440: 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a  dauQ"_100000G$v.
00000450: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c                ,,
00000470: 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122  "79-egnufetniuQ"
00000480: 5f31 3030 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c  _1000000G$!v@,,,
00000490: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,,,.      
000004a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004c0: 2020 2020 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665        "79-egnufe
000004d0: 7470 6553 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765  tpeS"_"Sexefunge
000004e0: 2d39 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  -97"#@,,,,,,,,,,
000004f0: 2c2c 4023 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,@#,.          
00000500: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000510: 2020 2020 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22       <>"v"@. @,"
00000520: 4622 2c22 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22  F","u","n","c","
00000530: 7422 2c22 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e  t","o","i","d"<>
00000540: 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265   red down two re
00000550: 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f  d left one yello
00000560: 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20  w up green down 
00000570: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20  yellow up green 
00000580: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265  down red up thre
00000590: 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20  e red right two 
000005a0: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c  yellow down yell
000005b0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
000005c0: 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564  t green down red
000005d0: 2064 6f77 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77   down one yellow
000005e0: 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420   down blue left 
000005f0: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064  green down red d
00000600: 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674  own two red left
00000610: 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079   one yellow up y
00000620: 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520  ellow down blue 
00000630: 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20  left green down 
00000640: 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564  red left one red
00000650: 2064 6f77 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c   down three yell
00000660: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
00000670: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
00000680: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020  een down red up 
00000690: 7477 6f20 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079  two green down y
000006a0: 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  ellow up yellow 
000006b0: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072  down blue left r
000006c0: 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420  ed up three red 
000006d0: 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77  right two yellow
000006e0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77   down yellow dow
000006f0: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 740a 2e4c 2020  n blue left..L  
00000700: 2020 2020 2020 2020 202e 2e20 2020 2a2f           ..   */
00000710: 2f2f 7b7d 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f  //{}]........lao
00000720: 6372 6168 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  crahC...........
00000730: c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3  ................
00000740: 9fe2 86a8 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286  ................
00000750: 90c3 9fe2 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2  ................
00000760: 8690 e289 a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83  ................
00000770: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286  ................
00000780: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2  ................
00000790: 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
000007a0: c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2  ................
000007b0: 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
000007c0: e286 92e2 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
000007d0: 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2  ................
000007e0: 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286  ................
000007f0: 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2  ................
00000800: e28c 82e2 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286  ................
00000810: 92e2 86a8 c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000820: c2a1 cf80 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2  ................
00000830: a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296  ................
00000840: b2c2 a1ce b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2  ................
00000850: 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2  ................
00000860: a1c2 bb2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e  ...++++[-<+++++>
00000870: 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b  ]<[-<++++++<++++
00000880: 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b  +<+++++>>>]<<<++
00000890: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c  +++++.>-.>---.<<
000008a0: 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d  -----.++++++++.-
000008b0: 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b  ----.>--.>---.<+
000008c0: 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829  .>>>((((((((((()
000008d0: 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  ()()){}){}){}){}
000008e0: 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829  ()){})((()()()()
000008f0: 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b  ){}){})[(([][]){
00000900: 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d  }){}()])([]()){}
00000910: 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d  )[]())(([[][]()]
00000920: 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d  ([]()((((([][][]
00000930: 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b  )){}{})[]){})))[
00000940: 5d28 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28  ]())({ -}_=")";(
00000950: 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420  !)=seq;main|let 
00000960: 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224 2822  b!_=""=putStr$("
00000970: 2221 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b  "!"snrettaPgnaB+
00000980: 2229 2b2b 696e 6974 226c 6c65 6b73 6148  ")++init"lleksaH
00000990: 2822 7b2d 0a2f 2f48 4854 2d40 5e73 7245  ("{-.//HHT-@^srE
000009a0: 7152 4d4d 7e64 4f2d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f 2f2f  qRMM~dO-}--)*///
000009b0: f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1  ....ijome.......
000009c0: f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e  ....Emotinomicon
000009d0: f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b  .............@,k
000009e0: 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522       a"89-egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 4):

## 38. alphuck, 2656 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left
.L           ..   *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-@^srEqRMM~dO-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiij"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbbhtHls/qX5iXUlMxu0U2m5RsWaJIju62M7alsZzYG4nmNLuLZEt9YfpCSZEVBDNAgAEWm8E8BIt92CDA7mIvsw8TTB4GmyfPe/IP@oGdP/CeU1V94UW2k9mW2Kw69zp1quqcZneNcPD6dYFsWhYxCO0bcd8zHpLIh97Qdy76jh@RiIYRGRiBR8OQdC/IY5vufEJPTv2uVCDbvuMYw5ASedu3qEwMzyLyZtCPXepFoUxCaka274Wk5wekS6OIBoSeD2lgU8@kkmQaEWkRE3glxyNayJrsVun2SIFs0V7s9am2tixFfmwOyDCwQbAEqu0eufBjYqDticIycY1TSsI4oDgK17fs3gUBCyrDCxL6JBqAvmhAL4CFEtszndiiFjQQSBzbO5WoOfCJ5hF5oSaDaZw3B11CqOWH49BlhIa@61KtZ58jThpeRAPfWx6HJhz3AiMM61IUEM20yNmzEWkwJyBekh5uPr73wea93c6Dxzu7z5s1aevvnu4eNuUF5cwEBkaqyhK4hnmXOIbXj40@VdRLaY6pkAtkYVxKhSzUymSBSYJphFmVE9onsefZXp@wEd9akua6EBegh4225cfRMI4ErXDMy4COWjiPZkStRMwkXPMcaQ5maZ6Y7pBwMSRBklu3ZiOAax1nw5PmuNxngQ@2caoKuU/Prdgd1gF7fm6RxLieLc1NeA28pUz4oFRT1XTUGjn@1YKCAciFqMe/wkBgTmglcXaFkTaIomFY1/W@HQ3ibsX0Xf1pcPEg2vcgYqgeBRd25CdtSnXXCCHO9bPAGEKkhyAhmSAi42qSicxMYG0pw@0AwnItogWxx9ZAHnmIYQQEQQxrUPeHkc4Ci98rQXeKodVoAXkShYyjZ4cDdsPlMEm/DdSMytQi09S7tqfD92xjtmE/MH3DSVlEP23MUvCh7QL9yHbTdQ7tSgQh0NItOtK92HHIUutWDWMD50Wg8zL2u@/jjjKiGprbR/vOid89EUCTy9X8PIypAJEVfQKYF5xuNKvJmLophPmi1@3aU0PKtqcJLsYCbW7PSxIZtoMrqrS8luffg3DZ2T8k2/uPSM92aG7C@BaTJ77nOzPmtO87bFrDwEzas5z/gZcf4PCCdYimhZHVXFuFRiwIbh7j3SnP3NXcqGfreAMJCfBmCStvkZCCV6ZkdAPD9nqxeZqKSABZa4rpafCWQUfBDYNmMrWeY4zrGxigbwtb9w2hj2ibY4ywdcr8a0rofSM8pY7DFjGIYp0pok8Y/ycz2Knrn9iT08@A/D5r2oXK0hZADgw8fr1wXL/2PI@bXumlEi60UgkXmglfyQIzh8NsYYlOnnHX9SPb813b9D3c8M6HfhCRx/s7u52Dzaf3m8eyHoeB7thd3QORHTirY4eGxzJKREg6vlTMWKdyMm3sKfPd6QzfWXxarFnTkkXJO0f4GyJn07HN8X3aQIgOxwkNhgGF@6zd@pexYf0UOz7O@KZkrq0lctbWdDjhaXSB9xm60bifojvlm5IZXrhdHwZO8gvX9T1fnF3dHn4q9JyzzjoCGDVLBYFq7CiE/o@3Nky4pm2F05uGiSTe0yNIKmmkB9ShRkgFdPpUpsPoJ9kyvMlxe5jU@baVCOuJftqY4mC55FjE9RHC77NizXCGg5k7qUCQiu1hsgW5pQx5LGZCPVI89hoQvi2WfLaKaXqLaSIm9yYmT/6QekoRKYpqJaCGpah1xq@YmK/7gaWYaqu5vIR1Au81akt3sWfCoo9ARrHRurVQpA7UFL3ircIlp7paL5apZzWLRUjgEosaOrOloaNdx96xd8CStjo2i6y0EFmcYJCPvSNI3IgNKR9L1@bbR08f7LeR/jE9j6B6Cc@gQHFjqHjQGnpuUkhVMZFkeXOrtrz8c95crC3rtWqdd0q3q6rKk@oKCisUkjwVe7KEmSqa@jIEacVQf6ETuPRizrfMkHqaamLZAZu0XihknualyOvXIwwCfVG71DRSGDyZf65tkIMXg08/fb6xUd0h1R15MOLAjwak9PwOkR/NPyLUgQl4tL9NDvd3KA32Fq5KcB0t6joEwbFE9BIpwBccXNQzXIiSBQUnEGsiAg72TX1hQYclpLIkf73eaBR39/eKpNBqHUu1EoghU9f@saQvkp/1@@Y91/7wZx99tO77vuz49@T1nzer7x3O12oAaLBUVSpYtIe70yFmovzS9U2pYPcAQTodc@jEIX503ZFIT1HX86p03QZSXtA1TDjgbb@l62ZOaqkEcnWdShBkUd5cUA2hZfdS0HEl07q/9f52p5M3TqMjOzLp@939hFGCqtP2oPji06kcqvqiLkC2y849MKjCjFqHLL9yFtgR1RcX9fUrffGqIbUIGZ09g4vdnp1h5@zHN56dZVcqLPlKv/Ot8c4Y/AbIO4Kenc0CPkttuwH17GYUv6S1tTXCP1kTW6NGSxoRAoGUpXzl5Lp7sayNGmQDHV14cW80FagbZXlL7kAmADwbEgBGjaOO3M6l961UWLn6cqOBNK1CI5/atsiL0cK9arWGdjBC@e6aRvte3KNbMulML48Rm3lGulHgoBxP8FTujKCMB5HVGoyOvPFqtGpAV723MOKEhY3y2LVRyEm2jPiXcocxZBw3XvmBRJ6dsQLv/GhMz1skjV85qUN6CO4fO9fHB7BReKtsmPqRDJMHc7knl@UYPh58TPhE8PHhY8PHkhstEsA@bPlnHonOfNZxaA8PBUouICf2z0g8JH2ozTxONROIbACJBgBincDuDyImUdDneVm768SUq5qQwxo59e9A/QbL30lIypdJZCP50bajD8CWme6aLeBv8ZxUeZib80oFbniEXV61r//hn/73u3979WfH8M3AGGy/@q/rL795lf5d//2vrz//9@//CLe/fAW3DHb9@e8A8tt/uf7yu@vPf8/uv7v@7b9im@F/@A02xT9jzno/fJbrCdirr//y1auv0@73f5rByOi@Hef64XOk/hZEMrXjYgTJZ2DMl98kBD/85tW3ggR63/8xa//wGbSBkP2PNZkAIP4TU5jAOexbHPyX3736@tX/sORAa@BXqdVuJM1SI3dvtQDTEIhSpaXBv6ZVGg0Nr0opQfBuS0vwQNpqKdml4p96eZX@816CSXFHinLUPmonNG0VuhzJvgGLaEAwOBONAOAAGkaFtKqgviTaVacpq/K6Mq82Q/rxOh7ZLx0ake48IOQm5MCHUbCgyPK8HHpQukXGQd8ztkqyWirZnh3JjkNPQ@O@Il9qkq7fv/9U23gRBrsfP3n06FNrX7vSNBWj869f/f4P9onvUmxc//PXf/3qH/87Xx9D/5vrL/7z@os/XH/xHxvlU0NeTbZG74MQLwMvml7DXNu0w6R3YovrhE5dKW6cgIHzuBP5dS/wXfIJVOaEZy@LkshiMDlcuS31mo7hdi2DeHWW8HvlYtBNE37JanaL@Pzj@LzXw0@x1FOKFVbIQQpbVEvdYobi7WLlxId0qafsqVhL7EGKdsTLiHKRp73Q4E/EoJF/ol5sq5LZNH0XaoAw9Lsnylp5Z3fv4ebT3Z2y9mjzeefZ1oOnhwjrPNp91Hm4@@Huw3JV5am3wkdU6a7cph7qU8xKIkux1JJZ6UHCOVDUcre4ocMQLcqoYKxhFNhDpdgsqurrAtnZP9Qc@5SS89UV4kJsuIZDqBs7RoQ/fEz8agKZOP7ekP7EcuYHpyEZ0ICWsTg5s6EKRhiWVOBUB8WXwftBgI/pu3E/5EKA1vJp6BW5CCEBfxWBhL1rdJ0L4mEBE/lQykSQqwJH9ssJQw2oMwSF0UBQoIJoYIfE6MIIDfb7QpkY4SlxafI7iYn@h7qK@D12gsCXeyGKJwB6XIA5MGB5wGkuJeETXoQSiy1eyvpOKAKMDI0gsg1HkpgluSqSRxboJ726NAejgqLWJU3SS4LNpa4PJV2THD0GU9qLK3fuLK8I6NHSnZU6fEpghiJ41TbQirZkUSdtSwHt2/jcPgSCy@KDg2KdVM8h0SmT4uGDXGf7OetUq3t7ZWmuuINd1I10B1l750HSBqLNhIdJ2MqxbCUsV1LPMfpc@fYeAPcMqIGBYj/f@SjfOcx3DtLOlSRh7UKDwA8UN@yrzHMY7T1598mT/Sd1cgngK/hKxzwfXMmqNAczVKHndqTUVC6kT6MOTkQHi1sFJWEDjBQeTgUcocfabfaDDyOBCMBh1YUdRcjtzDjC8Io9XkxZQkgRFE/IIaUmqSE0igOPyZsw5wwfC6A5jg/GTFgpzQ3sWVAhTgFso0FWVVIiji9JT3bvHWIA4Szx@cXpY/ctdodp5TPFQ4FPbhv57m8@3EPey2SOFS6EzYNaJgWy@RBQ2xy1PY7afpiEj8LVZagdRG1x1NY4agtRLNCErqdBLFTdR6aDTFWK2UYMC2KhKcXsIGbnQaYoxWzdl0QgwWboOyP2hDZwV5nXA7cM4D6MfAxZW0E348YU2l4YGZ5JFSSFnQS5gA04ErcdBW6bTfwYjPbb6UQJLTOsQEUgkLVnzfTW5uEuTulRMoMwX2WS9HaS3sEY7iCPS6A52kQCRjlsg50kZrn9h0fcGl0nq@Q9stpm5rGlksDh6OQu4BAgYs7iZE2yzFzEh84EgoPKJK9JmsPnYkiG5xYIqkITD0z0ImzOOGzkQgqUnK0q9OvUkoy9kEYpEQqw4QAIqBmJlUkM04STEBeoUFlqTghNbLkFxsBB3utJ0lx@UNXUFhe7K6ybjHJiOU8Odi4dbsqBunhQIDKnp8bIkhXObZ2MC5XcEkZOaUoVGWFI4UBKxC69SSq3@kapyY61qgCo4wcdcCpG7cT6SHHAHg8dylcK7ZfJAMoitsQSCkBYRmTwiIc1ABiVuxtJ8x5gZBBy7NDKjy@Pfy9BJ1ghPNvbhd42V8LQSRCx6WFx1JPxLOY7OwZUEjsRiL/MhNSrS@fskMnbwJ0UjjupzFB/s6t8x3qTp8IEUSYKG1lyJiCfcI2ad12OgdFzSj75jDShnPYf2AG@sftw6K0yZdnxykW@U3gk26iYprGF@JNmKl36uWmanqJ0XOysnRkc7LydwoCHasIgYBXmENiugPz/L4wmj3MRUGN@fZeISg@pWW7NTSAI5jM47pdJdLa6uHem8LnVOTNgYCwzMMyngB3YYqQiqBLxYoxJl7RAyd1ePQNozUSt8F@CycsDI98ssDdL5I1Cs9jPZApCISJx1hg5WPEW@oQDJzTonJhmJxxAPaFATW3ZWLpwTmdWjsDORyd1ELYz39j45oaQUSczslMgz6u2odSrrXSW/SFLTMLArEHMhdHsDAnRgElHybcBhKocuzSBHTtvcERh7KBsJmgRv5byOTQonohYzgGsrMg4wgqjndcxzquSeWY3sKQcH3GOHH9@/Od@wDNDYC@jPZMDX2Xjxn2eUfRFSyUveBtYVLEpDqHiTlZJfaw0ODxgNnB3YU8lGh7R6XLPE5YnV1wi3h@K9HHsLM0JBUunyxsUicpx17oJnyxOTjNt@DT5kjR9GoqIgnqNrT18byCIh9ENMZzDY/QusYQrreP4sTSDjOVLWIdzsatKvppQRTWB8jkN8lTX2G4t3tdrkmKRJUyWFWRzAtUFSxbPBrZDmTCevnn0DIjMQaAwZcikMkLOz8s9nigyUpC@AEVJF46EU4YQWoEQ8AjhFS0HJz8N509rcagUP/BsF1IFfGDB3vSMlmokfXESThZsszOlmNvRb2QWPgS@tJMyS2ziYvHCKysKwdFWnfCnZXVxKnE/99M2xvDkEi8j63K1nltdHHTn7dJezJJWAJNvV0FT9fzOHr4zC8PpUsc/Q6krq5lUsfhmGrSyVp/a7hji7komYHIrzm84cPTndhMu1LTqWcRjyZl0TF4aikeN0KmTXAaWpXW46FTBZdF35tIyLhzzNFvmCcGSkvvDNyoRG4wqYWUGFRU9LycFGvVilwYGLF4s8HB5s/eiWVGTix4k/cQeKoHh9amCM1eGiVuB@yoUSUd5Dwk@MfKkJ0aUdpnFbZbe5IP0SFQ0zEj2YIw/h1NyRMx22DrHVjTDz9qQouAClQwMz3JYZTymjnUgI8T3KmAV/YJe7OJCy604OfZOPfzBJ8dX58sN@mnuJ@Qr6uvJB4bps0KTF9/Jg8JKOHRgPywee7BU8bkf4o802K4LwBHGLn/wSfnr2vydJFs8zKQw03CU4xsjEn8tCATLm6FdXy3V60ul@u27i5pbXpeldG@UZT77ZXN82jk7SxGa/M0WbXmJR4GDlKi3LlJmGJOjQn5i10ONETtHdpvTZ7shbqnhe2t3SstLyTNt/qowFyWXxcvN/wc)

Next answer must not exceed 3452 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 705c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  /op\. /+ #\. bas
00000060: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
00000070: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000080: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000090: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
000000b0: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
000000c0: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
000000d0: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
000000e0: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
000000f0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000100: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000110: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
00000120: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
00000130: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
00000140: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
00000150: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
00000160: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
00000170: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000180: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000190: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
000001a0: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
000001b0: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
000001c0: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
000001d0: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
000001e0: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
000001f0: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000200: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000210: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
00000220: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
00000230: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
00000240: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000250: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000280: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
000002c0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002f0: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000300: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000310: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265  9.999v<>.v  <>"e
00000320: 6675 6e67 652d 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-98",,,,,,,
00000330: 2c2c 3779 332d 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e  ,,7y3-v< @.>  #^
00000340: 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  Gv              
00000350: 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40     @,"B"_"Tr",,@
00000360: 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67  .   v<[_"]Befung
00000370: 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  e-93">,,,,,,,,,,
00000380: 307c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675  0|@<.   >#<"Befu
00000390: 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031  nge-96"> ^v$G001
000003a0: 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e  .v  ,,,,,"79-egn
000003b0: 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020  ufeB" _         
000003c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c           v<.>  ,
000003d0: 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739  ,,,,@#      ,"79
000003e0: 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447  -egnuferT"_v# $G
000003f0: 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020  0001<>.         
00000400: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000410: 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a       <>10000G$v.
00000420: 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c       #@,,,,,,,,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566  ,,,,,@#"79-egnuf
00000440: 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724  erdauQ"_100000G$
00000450: 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  v.              
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000470: 2c2c 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975  ,,"79-egnufetniu
00000480: 5122 5f31 3030 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c  Q"_1000000G$!v@,
00000490: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,,,,,.    
000004a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75          "79-egnu
000004d0: 6665 7470 6553 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e  fetpeS"_"Sexefun
000004e0: 6765 2d39 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  ge-97"#@,,,,,,,,
000004f0: 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,@#,.        
00000500: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000510: 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040         <>"v"@. @
00000520: 2c22 4622 2c22 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322  ,"F","u","n","c"
00000530: 2c22 7422 2c22 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422  ,"t","o","i","d"
00000540: 3c3e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20  <> red down two 
00000550: 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c  red left one yel
00000560: 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77  low up green dow
00000570: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565  n yellow up gree
00000580: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468  n down red up th
00000590: 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477  ree red right tw
000005a0: 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965  o yellow down ye
000005b0: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c  llow down blue l
000005c0: 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072  eft green down r
000005d0: 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c  ed down one yell
000005e0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
000005f0: 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564  t green down red
00000600: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
00000610: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
00000620: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75   yellow down blu
00000630: 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77  e left green dow
00000640: 6e20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072  n red left one r
00000650: 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965  ed down three ye
00000660: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77  llow down yellow
00000670: 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420   down blue left 
00000680: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075  green down red u
00000690: 7020 7477 6f20 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  p two green down
000006a0: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
000006b0: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
000006c0: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
000006d0: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
000006e0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
000006f0: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 740a 2e4c  own blue left..L
00000700: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 202e 2e20 2020             ..   
00000710: 2a2f 2f2f 7b7d 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c  *///{}]........l
00000720: 616f 6372 6168 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2  aocrahC.........
00000730: c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286  ................
00000740: a8c3 9fe2 86a8 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
00000750: e286 90c3 9fe2 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296  ................
00000760: bce2 8690 e289 a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
00000770: cf83 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000780: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286  ................
00000790: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
000007a0: c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce  ................
000007b0: b4e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
000007c0: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692  ................
000007d0: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf  ................
000007e0: 80e2 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692  ................
000007f0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2  ................
00000800: 96b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1  ................
00000810: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2  ................
00000820: 86a8 c2a1 cf80 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000830: b2c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83  ................
00000840: e296 b2c2 a1ce b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000850: b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296  ................
00000860: bcc2 a1c2 bb2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  .....++++[-<++++
00000870: 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  +>]<[-<++++++<++
00000880: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c  +++<+++++>>>]<<<
00000890: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
000008a0: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
000008b0: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
000008c0: 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  <+.>>>((((((((((
000008d0: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29  ()()()){}){}){})
000008e0: 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829  {}()){})((()()()
000008f0: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d  ()){}){})[(([][]
00000900: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929  ){}){}()])([]())
00000910: 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28  {})[]())(([[][](
00000920: 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d  )]([]()((((([][]
00000930: 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929  [])){}{})[]){}))
00000940: 295b 5d28 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922  )[]())({ -}_=")"
00000950: 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65  ;(!)=seq;main|le
00000960: 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224  t b!_=""=putStr$
00000970: 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61  (""!"snrettaPgna
00000980: 422b 2229 2b2b 696e 6974 226c 6c65 6b73  B+")++init"lleks
00000990: 6148 2822 7b2d 0a2f 2f48 4854 2d40 5e73  aH("{-.//HHT-@^s
000009a0: 7245 7152 4d4d 7e64 4f2d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f  rEqRMM~dO-}--)*/
000009b0: 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2  //....ijome.....
000009c0: 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963  ......Emotinomic
000009d0: 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940  on.............@
000009e0: 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5573  ,ka"89-egnufenUs
000009f0: 7373 7373 6161 6161 6165 6565 6565 6565  ssssaaaaaeeeeeee
00000a00: 6565 6570 6165 6565 6565 6565 6565 6563  eeepaeeeeeeeeeec
00000a10: 6973 6165 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 6969  isaeeeeeeejiiiii
00000a20: 6969 696a 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  iiijeeeeeeeeeeee
00000a30: 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 6969 6969 6969  eeeeeejiiiiiiiii
00000a40: 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6565 6565 656a 6969  iiiijeeeeeeeejii
00000a50: 6969 6a69 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a22  iijiiiiiiiiiiij"
```

## Changes

Added alphuck code near the end,  and some scattered throughout the code. Capitalized the `J` for Objective-C, to avoid output. The `sssss` is to balance five open `p`s (those are alphuck's `[]`).

Answer (score 4):

## 39. Canvas, 2667 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left
.L           ..   *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-@^srEqRMM~dO-}--)*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiij"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in Canvas

[Try Canvas online!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=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_,v=3)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbcttGls/CL8xLC1RMQCQIUrJliSIZ3W1nbEtjKbbXEs0BgSYJCRcGF0qyrFRqpiq1U7W1Sc1DancfNpWq3a29zD5MavIwtdkXz3v8D/qBmT/wntPdAMGLbCezkAh2n3ufPt19Doi2EfbevMmRdcsiBqFdI@56xn0S@dDr@8551/EjEtEwIj0j8GgYkvY5eWjTrRf0@MRvSzmy6TuO0Q8pkTd9i8rE8Cwirwfd2KVeFMokpGZk@15IOn5A2jSKaEDoWZ8GNvVMKkmmEZEGMYFXcjyihazJbqV2h@TIBu3EXpdqK4tS5Mdmj/QDGwRLoNrukHM/JgbanigsEtc4oSSMA4qjcH3L7pwTsKDUPyehT6Ie6It69BxYKLE904ktakEDgcSxvROJmj2faB6R5yoymMZ5M9AFhFp@OApdRGjouy7VOvYZ4qT@edTzvcVRaMJxJzDCsCpFAdFMi5w@GZAacwLiJen@@sM7H6/f2W7de7i1/bRekTb@5mB7vy7PKacmMDBSVZbANcy7xDG8bmx0qaJeSDNMhZwjc6NSSmSuUiRzTBJMI8yqnNA@ij3P9rqEjfjGgjTThrgAPWy0DT@O@nEkaIVjXgZ00MB5NCNqJWLG4ZrnSDMwS7PEdPuEiyEJkty4MR0BXKs4G540w@U@CXywjVOVyF16ZsVuvwrYszOLJMZ1bGlmzGvgLWXMB4WKqqaj1sjRL@cUDEAuRD36JQYCc0IjibNLjLReFPXDqq537agXt0um7@oHwfm9aNeDiKF6FJzbkZ@0KdVdI4Q4108Dow@RHoKEZIKIjKtJJjIzgbWlIW4LEJZrES2IPbYGssh9DCMgCGJYg7rfj3QWWPxeCtoTDI1aA8iTKGQcHTvssRsuh3H6TaBmVKYWmabetj0dvqcbswn7gekbTsoi@mljmoLHtgv0A9tN1zm0SxGEQEO36ED3YschC40bFYwNnBeBzsrYbX@EO8qAamhuF@07I377WABNLlfzszCmAkSW9DFgVnC60SwnY2qnEOaLTrttTwxpuD2NcTEWaHN7XpLIsB1cUYXFlSz/DoTL1u4@2dx9QDq2QzMTxreYLPEd35kyp13fYdMaBmbSnub8j73sAPvnrEM0LYys@soyNGJBcP0Yb0945rbmRh1bxxtISIDXS1h6h4QUvDQhox0YtteJzZNURAIYtiaYDoJ3DDoKrhk0k6l1HGNUX88AfRvYumsIfURbH2GErVPmXxNC7xrhCXUctohBFOtMEL1g/C@msFPXP7bHp58B@X3atAuVhQ2A7Bl4/HrhqH7taRY3udILBVxohQIuNBO@kgVm9vvDhSU6WcZt149sz3dt0/dwwzvr@0FEHu5ubbf21g/u1o9kPQ4D3bHbugciW3BWxw4Nj2SUiJB0fKmYkU7peNLYE@a7kym@s/i0WNOmZRgl7x3hb4mcdcc2R/dpAyE6HCc06AcU7tN261/EhvVT7PhkyDchc2UlkbOyosMJT6NzvE/Rjcb9FN0p34TM8Nxt@zBwkl24ru/54uxqd/BTomecddoRwKhZKghUI0ch9H@8tWHCNWkrnN40TCTxnh5BUkkjPaAONUIqoJOnMu1HP8mW/nWO28GkzretRFhH9NPGBAfLJUcirosQfp8Wa4bT703dSQWClGwPky3ILUe2gvWHj9f3k@Rlf/3xw/VNmWe08sPdg@0q2TS8gRESN4aKoU1ZfgOZnuObhuNAyh2lmZT1wrBdoyQSKtvXOaf@IQSBDKkzJl8dkj/yarBiGizfbeTTjBozU6wnTMzX/D71lDxS5NVSQA1LUauMXzGxRPADSzHVRn1xAUsT3qtVFm5jz4R9JgIZ@VrjxlyeOlDGdPI3chec6nI1X6SeVc/nIWdMLKrpzJaajnYdeUfeHssTq9jMs2pGJI6CQT7yDiFXJDZkmSxDnG0eHtzbbSL9Q3oWQcEUnkJNxFyG1tAzk4LPMHdlqXqjsrj4IW/OVxb1SrnKO4WbZVXleXwJheVySWqMPVnC5BhNfRmCtHyoP9cJXHo@41tmSDWdE6x04FzQc7mhp3n18@bNAONOn9cuNI3keo9mn2prZO9579NPn66tlbdIeUvuDTjwWY8Unt4i8oPZB4Q6MAEPdjfJ/u4WpcHO3GUBrsN5XYe4O5KIXiA5@IKzknqGCxE2p@AEYhlGwMG@qc/N6bBqVVZXrFZrtfz27k6e5BqNI6lSADFk4to9kvR58rNu17zj2o9/9uzZqu/7suPfkVc/rJc/2J@tVABQY9mxlLNoBzfEfUx@@aXr61LO7gCCtFpm34lD/Oi6I5GOoq5mVem6DaS8hqyZkFPYfkPXzYzUQgHk6jqVIMiirLmgGkLL7qSgo9JQ6@7GR5utVtY4jQ7syKQftXcTRgkKXduDeo9Pp7Kv6vO6ANkuO2rBoBIzahUKi9JpYEdUn5/XVy/1@cua1CBkcPoELnZ7coqd0x/feHI6vFJhyVf6nW2Ndkbg10DeE/TkdBrwSWrbNagn16P4Ja2srBD@GTaxNag1pAEhEEjDLLOYXLfPF7VBjayho3PP7wwmAnWtKG/ILUg@gGdNAsCgdtiSm5mKopEKK5ZfrtWQppGrZbPpBnk@mLtTLlfQDkYo317RaNeLO3RDJq3J5TFgM89I13IclOEJDuTWIEdQZLkCoyNvvWqNCtCV78wNOGFurThyreUyki0j/oXcYgxDjmuv7EAizx6yAu/sYETPOySNXhmpfboP7h9JJUYHsJZ7p2yY@oEMkwdzuSMX5Rg@HnxM@ETw8eFjw8eSaw0SwD5s@aceiU591nFoBw8FSs4hDfdPSdwnXSgHPU41FYhsAIl6AGKdwO72IiZR0Gd5WbvtxJSrGpPDGhn170H9FsvfS0jKN5TIRvKjbUcfgC1T3TVdwF/jOal0PzPnpRLc8Ai7uGxe/f0//fn7f3v1R8fwzcDobb76r6uvvn2V/l393a@uPv/3H34Ptz99Dbch7OrzLwHym3@5@ur7q89/y@5fXv3mX7HN8K9/jU3xz5iHvdefZXoC9uqbP3396pu0@8MfpjAyuu9GuV5/jtTfgUimdlSMIPkMjPnq24Tg9a9ffSdIoPfD74ft159BGwjZ/0iTCQDiPzCFCZzDvsPBf/X9q29e/Q9LDrQafhUazVrSLNQy90YDMDWBKJQaGvxrWqlW0/AqFRIE7za0BA@kjYYyvFT8Uy8u03/eSzAp7lBRDpuHzYSmqUKXI9k3YBENCAZnohEAHEDDqJBWFdQXRLts1WVVXlVm1XpIP1nFI/ulQyFdngWEXIe0ez8K5hRZnpVDD6rFyNjresZGQVYLBduzI9lx6Elo3FXkC03S9bt3D7S152Gw/cmjBw8@tXa1S01TITqv/vYfeYL@5//98i9f//Z39rHvUmxc/fM3f/n6H/47W51D/9urL/7z6ovfXX3xH2vFE0NeTnZJ7@MQLwMvml79TNu0w6R3bIvrmE5cKW6UgIGzuGP5TSfwXfLCsduEJzLzkkhoME9cuil16o7hti2DeFWW@3vFfNBOc3/Jqrfz@PTl6KzTwU@@0FHyJVZGQjabVwvt/BDF2/nSsQ@ZU0fZUbGs2IFs7ZBXFMU8z4ChwZ/HQSP7PD/fVCWzbvoulANh6LePlZXi1vbO/fWD7a2i9mD9aevJxr2DfYS1Hmw/aN3ffrx9v1hWeRau8BGV2ks3qYf6FLOUyFIstWCWOpB79hS12M6v6TBEizIqGGsYBXZfydfzqvomR7Z29zXHPqHkbHmJuBAmruEQ6saOEeHPLmO/2UBSjr92pD/wnPrBSUh6NKBFrFNObajBEYbVFTjVQfFF8H4Q4I8E7bgbciFAa/k09PJchJCAv8lA7t422lDyeVjLRD5UNRGkrcAx/N2GoXrU6YPCqCcoUEHUs0NitGGEBvt1o0iM8IS4NPmVxkT/Q4lF/A47TODLPRd1FAA9LsDsQc1J4WCXkvAJz0OJxRYvpH0nFAFG@kYQ2YYjScySTEHJIwv0k05VmoFRQUntkjrpJMHmUteH6q5ODh@CKc35pVu3FpcE9HDh1lIVPgUwQxG8ahNoRVuyqJO2pYB2bfzVIASCi/y9vXyVlM8g5ymS/P69TGfzKeuUyzs7RWkmv4Vd1I10e8P21r2kDUTrCQ@TsJFh2UhYLqWOY3S58s0dAO4YUA4DxW628yzb2c929tLOpSRhGUODwA8UN@yqzHMY7R15@9Gj3UdVcgHgS/hKxzwbXMqqNAMzVKJndqRUVC6kS6MWTkQL61wFJWEDjBQeTgUcoseaTfZzEyOBCMBhVYUdeUjzzDjC8Io9XldZQkgeFI/JIYU6qSA0igOPyRsz5xSfEKA5jg/GjFkpzfTsaVAhTgFsrUaWVVIgji9Jj7bv7GMA4Szx@cXpY/cNdodp5TPFQ4FPbhP57q7f30Hei2SOFS6EzYNaJDmyfh9Qmxy1OYravJ@Ej8LVDVFbiNrgqI1R1AaiWKAJXQdBLFTdRaa9oaoUs4kYFsRCU4rZQszWvaGiFLNxVxKBBJuh7wzY8@HAXWZeD9wigLsw8hFkZQndjBtTaHthZHgmVZAUdhLkAjbgSNx2GLhNNvEjMNptphMltEyxAhWBQNaeNtMb6/vbOKWHyQzCfBVJ0ttKensjuL0sLoFmaBMJGOWwDbaSmOX27x9ya3SdLJMPyHKTmceWSgKHo5O7gEOAiDmLk9XJInMRHzoTCA4qkqwmaQYfkSEZnlsgqAxNPDDRi7A547CRCylQ8nBVoV8nlmTshTRKiVCADQdAQM1IrEximCachLhAhcpCfUxoYssNMAYO8k5HkmaygyqntrjYXWLdZJRjy3l8sDPpcFMO1MWDApEZPRVGlqxwbut4XKjkhjByQlOqyAhDCgdSInbhbVK51ddKTXasZQVALT9ogVMxasfWR4oD9rjvUL5SaLdIelAhsSWWUADCMiKDRzysAcCo3N1ImvUAI4OQY4dWdnxZ/AcJOsEK4cO9XehtciUMnQQRmx4WRx0Zz2K@s2NAJbETgfiLoZBqeeGMHTJZG7iTwlEnFRnqr3aV71hv81SYIIpEYSNLzgTkE65Rs67LMDB6Tsknn5EmlJP@AzvAN3YXDr1lpmx4vHKR7xUeyTYqpmlkIf6kmUqXfmaaJqcoHRc7a6cGBztvJzDgoYowCFiFOQS2KyD//wuj8eNcBNSIX98notJDappbMxMIgvkMjvplHD1cXdw7E/jM6pwaMDCWKRjmU8D2bDFSEVSJeDHGpEsaoOR2pzoEaPVErfBfgsnKAyPfLrAzTeS1QoexP5QpCIWIxFkj5GDFO@gTDpzQoHVsmq2wB/WEAjW1ZWPpwjmdaTkCOx@d1EHYHvrGxvdGhIwqmZKdAnlWtQ2lXmWptej3WWISBmYFYi6MpmdIiAZMOkq@DSBU5diFMezIeYMjCmMHZTNB8/i1kM2hQfFYxHIOYGVFxiFWGM2sjlFelcwyu4El5XjGOTL82fGf@QHPDIG9iPaMD3yZjRv3eUbRFS2VPOdtYFHFptiHijtZJdWR0mB/j9nA3YU9lWh4RKfLPUtYHF9xiXi/L9LHkbM0IxQsnSxvUCQqx13rOnyyODnNpOGT5AvS5GkoIgrqNbb28K2FIO5H18RwBo/Ru8ASrrSO48fSFDKWL2EdzsUuK9lqQhXVBMrnNMhTXmG7tXhbsE7yeZYwWVYwnBOoLliyeNqzHcqE8fTNo6dAZPYChSlDJpURcn5e7vFEkZGC9DkoStpwJJwwhNAKhIBHCK9oOTj5lTh7WotDJf@xZ7uQKuADC/aeabRQIelrm3CyYJudKfnMjn4ts/Ah8KWdlFliExeL121ZUQiOtqqEPy2rilOJ@7mbtjGGx5d4EVkXy9XM6uKgW@@W9nyatByYfLMMmspnt3bwjV0YTps6/ilKXVoeShWLb6pBSyvVie2OIW4vDQWMb8XZDQeO/sxuwoWaVnUY8VhyJh2Tl4biUSN0qiSTgQ3TOlx0quCy6HtzaUMuHPMk29ATgiUl9/tvVSI2GFXCygwqKnpWTAo06sUuDQxYvFjg4fJmb2WzoiYTPUj6wu4rgeF1qYIzV4SJW4L7MhRJh1kPCT4x8qQnRpR2mcVNlt5kg/RQVDTMSPZgjD@HUzJEzHbYOkdWNMNP25Ci4ByV9AzPclhlPKKOdSAjxFcsYBX9nJ5v40LLrDg59k48/O0nw1flyw36ae4n5Cvqm/EHhumzQpMX38mDwlLYd2A/zB95sFTxuR/iDzXYrnPAEcYuf/BJ@cvi/I0oWzzMpDDTcJTjyyMSfykJBMvroV1dLlSrC4XqzdvzmltclaV0b5RlPvtFc3TaOTtLEer8JRdtcYFHgYOUqLcqUmYYk6NCfmJXQ40RO4d2k9MPd0PcUsMPVm4VFheSZ9r8RWUuSi6KV6v/Dw)

Next answer must not exceed 3467 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 705c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  /op\. /+ #\. bas
00000060: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
00000070: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000080: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000090: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
000000b0: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
000000c0: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
000000d0: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
000000e0: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
000000f0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000100: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000110: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
00000120: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
00000130: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
00000140: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
00000150: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
00000160: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
00000170: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000180: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000190: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
000001a0: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
000001b0: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
000001c0: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
000001d0: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
000001e0: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
000001f0: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000200: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000210: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
00000220: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
00000230: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
00000240: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000250: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000280: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
000002c0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002f0: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000300: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000310: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265  9.999v<>.v  <>"e
00000320: 6675 6e67 652d 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-98",,,,,,,
00000330: 2c2c 3779 332d 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e  ,,7y3-v< @.>  #^
00000340: 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  Gv              
00000350: 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40     @,"B"_"Tr",,@
00000360: 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67  .   v<[_"]Befung
00000370: 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  e-93">,,,,,,,,,,
00000380: 307c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675  0|@<.   >#<"Befu
00000390: 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031  nge-96"> ^v$G001
000003a0: 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e  .v  ,,,,,"79-egn
000003b0: 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020  ufeB" _         
000003c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c           v<.>  ,
000003d0: 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739  ,,,,@#      ,"79
000003e0: 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447  -egnuferT"_v# $G
000003f0: 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020  0001<>.         
00000400: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000410: 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a       <>10000G$v.
00000420: 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c       #@,,,,,,,,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566  ,,,,,@#"79-egnuf
00000440: 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724  erdauQ"_100000G$
00000450: 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  v.              
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000470: 2c2c 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975  ,,"79-egnufetniu
00000480: 5122 5f31 3030 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c  Q"_1000000G$!v@,
00000490: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,,,,,.    
000004a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75          "79-egnu
000004d0: 6665 7470 6553 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e  fetpeS"_"Sexefun
000004e0: 6765 2d39 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  ge-97"#@,,,,,,,,
000004f0: 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,@#,.        
00000500: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000510: 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040         <>"v"@. @
00000520: 2c22 4622 2c22 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322  ,"F","u","n","c"
00000530: 2c22 7422 2c22 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422  ,"t","o","i","d"
00000540: 3c3e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20  <> red down two 
00000550: 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c  red left one yel
00000560: 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77  low up green dow
00000570: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565  n yellow up gree
00000580: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468  n down red up th
00000590: 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477  ree red right tw
000005a0: 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965  o yellow down ye
000005b0: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c  llow down blue l
000005c0: 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072  eft green down r
000005d0: 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c  ed down one yell
000005e0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
000005f0: 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564  t green down red
00000600: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
00000610: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
00000620: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75   yellow down blu
00000630: 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77  e left green dow
00000640: 6e20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072  n red left one r
00000650: 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965  ed down three ye
00000660: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77  llow down yellow
00000670: 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420   down blue left 
00000680: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075  green down red u
00000690: 7020 7477 6f20 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  p two green down
000006a0: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
000006b0: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
000006c0: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
000006d0: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
000006e0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
000006f0: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 740a 2e4c  own blue left..L
00000700: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 202e 2e20 2020             ..   
00000710: 2a2f 2f2f 7b7d 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c  *///{}]........l
00000720: 616f 6372 6168 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2  aocrahC.........
00000730: c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286  ................
00000740: a8c3 9fe2 86a8 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
00000750: e286 90c3 9fe2 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296  ................
00000760: bce2 8690 e289 a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
00000770: cf83 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000780: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286  ................
00000790: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
000007a0: c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce  ................
000007b0: b4e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
000007c0: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692  ................
000007d0: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf  ................
000007e0: 80e2 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692  ................
000007f0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2  ................
00000800: 96b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1  ................
00000810: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2  ................
00000820: 86a8 c2a1 cf80 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000830: b2c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83  ................
00000840: e296 b2c2 a1ce b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000850: b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296  ................
00000860: bcc2 a1c2 bb2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  .....++++[-<++++
00000870: 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  +>]<[-<++++++<++
00000880: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c  +++<+++++>>>]<<<
00000890: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
000008a0: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
000008b0: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
000008c0: 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  <+.>>>((((((((((
000008d0: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29  ()()()){}){}){})
000008e0: 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829  {}()){})((()()()
000008f0: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d  ()){}){})[(([][]
00000900: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929  ){}){}()])([]())
00000910: 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28  {})[]())(([[][](
00000920: 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d  )]([]()((((([][]
00000930: 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929  [])){}{})[]){}))
00000940: 295b 5d28 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922  )[]())({ -}_=")"
00000950: 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65  ;(!)=seq;main|le
00000960: 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224  t b!_=""=putStr$
00000970: 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61  (""!"snrettaPgna
00000980: 422b 2229 2b2b 696e 6974 226c 6c65 6b73  B+")++init"lleks
00000990: 6148 2822 7b2d 0a2f 2f48 4854 2d40 5e73  aH("{-.//HHT-@^s
000009a0: 7245 7152 4d4d 7e64 4f2d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f  rEqRMM~dO-}--)*/
000009b0: 2fe2 8899 5341 564e 4143 efbd 90f0 9f92  /...SAVNAC......
000009c0: ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e a1f0 9f98  .ijome..........
000009d0: ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f 6ef0 9f98  .Emotinomicon...
000009e0: b2e2 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 402c 6b61 2238  ..........@,ka"8
000009f0: 392d 6567 6e75 6665 6e55 7373 7373 7361  9-egnufenUsssssa
00000a00: 6161 6161 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 7061  aaaaeeeeeeeeeepa
00000a10: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6369 7361 6565  eeeeeeeeeecisaee
00000a20: 6565 6565 656a 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65  eeeeejiiiiiiiije
00000a30: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
00000a40: 656a 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 696a  ejiiiiiiiiiiiiij
00000a50: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 696a 6969  eeeeeeeejiiiijii
00000a60: 6969 6969 6969 6969 696a 22              iiiiiiiiij"
```

Answer (score 4):

## 40. [Nameless language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nameless_language), 3241 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
.L    . .         *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-"NUb4`BJJndO-}--)s*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiij"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbchtHds@cX9iX5oAWZggMhiAligQBmHdJjiRyRdpSDELwYKYBDDkX7Fx4Ec0tV7bKla1Kxa59cCV5iMtVSSqXzcO61g9bcV6079Y/8Ad2/0A5p7vnggsl2ZsRMeg@9z59uvucwahrhIPXrwtkw7KIQWjfiPue8ZBEPvSGvnPRd/yIRDSMyMAIPBqGpHtBHtt0@wU9PvG7UoFs@Y5jDENK5C3fojIxPIvIG0E/dqkXhTIJqRnZvheSnh@QLo0iGhB6PqSBTT2TSpJpRKRJTOCVHI9oIWuyW6XbIwWySXux16fa6pIU@bE5IMPABsESqLZ75MKPiYG2JwrLxDVOKAnjgOIoXN@yexcELKgML0jok2gA@qIBvQAWSmzPdGKLWtBAIHFs70Si5sAnmkfkuaoMpnHeHHQRoZYfjkKXEBr6rku1nn2OOGl4EQ18b2kUmnDcC4wwrElRQDTTImdPT0mdOQHxkvRw4/G9Dzfu7XQePN7eedaoSpt/fbhz0JDnlDMTGBipKkvgGuZd4hhePzb6VFEvpRmmQi6QuVEpFTJXLZM5JgmmEWZVTmifxJ5ne33CRnxrUZrpQlyAHjbaph9HwzgStMIxnwb0tInzaEbUSsSMwzXPkWZglmaJ6Q4JF0MSJLl1azoCuNZwNjxphst9GvhgG6eqkPv03IrdYQ2w5@cWSYzr2dLMmNfAW8qYD0pVVU1HrZGjT@YUDEAuRD36BAOBOaGZxNkVRtogioZhTdf7djSIuxXTd/XD4OJBtOdBxFA9Ci7syE/alOquEUKc62eBMYRID0FCMkFExtUkE5mZwNpShtsGhOVaRAtij62BPPIAwwgIghjWoO4PI50FFr9Xgu4EQ7PeBPIkChlHzw4H7IbLYZx@C6gZlalFpql3bU@H7@nGbMF@YPqGk7KIftqYpuAj2wX6U9tN1zm0KxGEQFO36KnuxY5DFpu3qhgbOC8CnZex1/0Ad5RTqqG5fbTvnPjdYwE0uVzNz8OYChBZ0ceAecHpRrOSjKmbQpgvet2uPTGkbHsa42Is0Ob2fEoiw3ZwRZWWVvP8uxAu23sHZGvvEenZDs1NGN9i8sT3fGfKnPZ9h01rGJhJe5rzP/TyAxxesA7RtDCyGqsr0IgFwc1jvDvhmbuaG/VsHW8gIQHeLGH5LRJS8PKEjG5g2F4vNk9SEQkga00wHQZvGXQU3DBoJlPrOcaovoEB@jaxdd8Q@oi2McIIW6fMvyaE3jfCE@o4bBGDKNaZIHrB@F9MYaeuf2yPTz8D8vu0aRcqS5sA2Tfw@PXCUf3aszxucqWXSrjQSiVcaCZ8JQvMHA6zhSU6ecYd149sz3dt0/dwwzsf@kFEHu9t73T2Nw7vN45kPQ4D3bG7ugciO3BWxw4Nj2SUiJB0fKmYkU7leNLYE@a7kym@s/i0WNOmJYuSd47wN0TOhmObo/u0gRAdjhMaDAMK92m79c9jw/opdvwi45uQubqayFld1eGEp9EF3qfoRuN@iu6Ub0JmeOF2fRg4yS9c1/d8cXZ1e/ip0HPOOu0IYNQsFQSqkaMQ@j/e2jDhmrQVTm8aJpJ4T48gqaSRHlCHGiEV0MlTmQ6jn2TL8CbH7WJS59tWIqwn@mljgoPlkiMR10cIv0@LNcMZDqbupAJBKraHyRbkliNbwcbjjzYOkuTlYOOjxxtbMs9o5cd7hzs1smV4p0ZI3Bgqhi5l@Q1keo5vGo4DKXeUZlLWC8N2jYpIqGxf55z6@xAEeZWe4YL/oe5IQInNCUK37BBGENuOlcFSLj5wieVyPVI88uqwAJssfW4W0wQdE10sT0xM//wh9ZQiUhTVSkANS1FrjF8xseLwA0sx1WZjaRErHd6rVxfvYs@EbSsCGcV689ZckTpQFfWKtwqXnOpqrVimntUoFiEFTSyq68yWuo52HXlH3j5LO2vYLLLiSOShgkE@8lqQehIbklaWcM62W4cP9tpI/5ieR1B/hWdQYrEZQGvouUlhCjAVZpl/s7q09D5vzleX9OpCjXdKtxdUlZcFFRRWKCSZNvZkCXNtNPXTEKQVQ/25TuDSiznfMkNq6RRj4QTHjF4oZJ7mxdTr16cYxvq8dqlppDB4MvtMWyf7zwe//OWz9fWFbbKwLQ9OOfDjASk9u0PkR7OPCHVgAh7tbZGDvW1Kg925qxJcrXldh5A4koheIgX4gqOXYgRAQaLgBGJVR8DBvqnPzemwCaisTFmr1evFnb3dIik0m0dStQRiyMS1dyTp8@Rn/b55z7U/@tnHH6/5vi87/j157f3GwnsHs9UqAOos2ZYKFu3h/nqAuTS/dH1DKtg9QJBOxxw6cYgfXXck0lPUtbwqXbeBlJekdRNSFNtv6rqZk1oqgVxdpxIEWZQ3F1RDaNm9FHRUybTubX6w1enkjdPoqR2Z9IPuXsIoQd1se1A@8ulUDlR9Xhcg22UnNxhUYUatQZ1SOQvsiOrz8/ralT5/VZeahJyePYWL3Z6eYefsxzeenmVXKiz5Sr/zrdHOCPwGyDuCnp5NAz5NbbsB9fRmFL@k1dVVwj9ZE1un9eYCXNUq/kmnhEBIZelrObnuXixpp3Wyji4vPL93OhGy62V5U@5AVgM86xIATuutjtzOlSrNVFh54dP1OtI0C/V8mt4kz0/n7oExaAcjlO@uarTvxT26KZPO5EI5ZTHASNcLHJTjCQ7lzmmBoMiFar0pkTde9WYVPXFv7pQTFtbLI9d6ISfZMuKfyx3GkHHceOUHEnl2xgq8s6cjet4iafTKSR3SA3D/SI4yOoD1wltlw9SfyjB5MJe7clmO4ePBx4RPBB8fPjZ8LLneJAHsyJZ/5pHozGcdh/bweKDkAvJ7/4zEQ9KHOtPjVFOByAaQaAAg1gns/iBiEgV9npe1u05MuaoxOayRU/8O1G@w/J2EpHyZRDaSH207@gBsmequ6QL@Is@x5c7ijwdhdaSF93wvT/Eu9JN0k3JyuOoN8qtvkrjwFo3voDfBVLN7@pVvTXxSAuFDTlzlvWrGK8gyXJ4nR/KjvxNFicop46tO8PxEfWKoUuUh7g8V@JdcmP9cXrWv//6f/vT9v738g2P4ZmAMtl7@1/VX375M/13/3d9cf/7vP/wObn/8Gm4Z7PrzLwHy63@5/ur7689/w@5fXv/6X7HN8K9@hU3xx5iz3qvPcj0Be/nNH79@@U3a/eH3UxgZ3XejXK8@R@rvQCRTOypGkHwGxnz1bULw6lcvvxMk0Pvhd1n71WfQBkL2N9JkAoD490xhAuew73DwX33/8puX/8MyS62OX6Vmu540S/XcvdkETF0gSpWmBn@aVqnXNbwqpQTBu00twQNps6lkl4r/1Mur9I/3EkyKaylKq91qJzRtFbocyb4Bi2hAMDgTjQDgABpGhbSqoL4k2lWnIavymjKrNkL6izXM9z51KJRus4CQG1ACHkTBnCLLs3LoBTSKjP2@Z2yWZLVUsj07kh2HnoTGfUW@1CRdv3//UJMff9i9/cnmBx941p52pWlqCOF5/bf/yKvFP/3vl3/@@je/tY99l2Lj@p@/@fPX//Df@UdF0P/2@ov/vP7it9df/Md6@cSQV5KT1fswxMvAi6bXMNc27TDpHdviOqYTV4obJWDgPO5Yft0LfJe8cOwu4WnwvCTSYawylm9LvYZjuF3LIF6NVY5euRh008pRshrdIj4KPDrv9fBTLPWUYoU904BaqKiWusUMxdvFyrEPeXdP2VWxKN2FXL/F69FykddP0OAPh6GR/3Gp2FYls2H6LhSTYeh3j5XV8vbO7sONw53tsvZo41nn6eaDwwOEdR7tPOo83Plo52F5QeU1nMJHVOku36Ye6lPMSiJLsdSSWelB5TJQ1HK3uK7DEC3KqGCsYRTYQ6XYKKrq6wLZ3jvQHPuEkvOVZeJCnLiGQ6gbO0aEvwGO/YAIJR3@9Jb@2njmBychGdCAlrHKPbMdh8GwNgenOii@DN4PAvzFqhv3Qy4EaC2fhl6RixAS8AdCqPy6Rte5IB5WwpEPNXEERQ9wZD8iMtSAOkNQGA0EBSqIBnZIjC6M0GA/tZWJEZ4QlyY/GZrofyjQid9jCQh8uReiCgegxwWYAwOWCiSDUhI@4UUosdjiT3V8JxQBRoZGENmGI0nMktzjCB5ZoJ/0atIMjKofGC5pkF4SbC51/eACIK3HYEp7fvnOnaVlAW0t3lmuwacEZiiCV20DrWhLFnXSthTQvo0/YYVAcFl8sF@skYVzOIDKpHjwINfZesY6Cwu7u2VppriNXdSNdPtZe/tB0gaijYSHSdjMsWwmLFdSzzH6XPnWLgB3DSdEir185@N85yDf2U87V5KERTANAj9Q3LCvMs9htPfknSdP9p7UyCWAr@ArHfNscCWr0gzMUIWe25FSVbmQPo06OBEdfEqioCRsgJHCw6mAFnqs3Wa/fTISiAAcVk3YUYTSwIwjDK/Y41W5JYQUQfGYHFJqkCpCozjwmLwxc87w@RKa4/hgzJiV0szAngYV4hTA1utkRSUl4viS9GTn3gEGEM4Sn1@cPnbfZHeYVj5TPBT45LaR7/7Gw13kvUzmWOFC2DyoZVIgGw8BtcVRW6OorYdJ@ChcXYbaRtQmR22OojYRxQJN6DoMYqHqPjLtZ6pSzBZiWBALTSlmGzHbDzJFKWbzviQCCTZD3zllP1YE7grzeuCWAdyHkY8gq8voZtyYQtsLI8MzqYKksJMgF7ABR@K2VuC22cSPwGi/nU6U0DLFClQEAll72kxvbhzs4JS2khmE@SqTpLed9PZHcPt5XALN0SYSMMphG@wkMcvtP2hxa3SdrJD3yEqbmceWSgKHo5O7gEOAiDmLkzXIEnMRHzoTCA4qk7wmaQYfsCIZnlsgaAGaeGCiF2FzxmEjF1Kg5GxVoV8nlmTshTRKiVCADQdAQM1IrEximCachLhAhcpSY0xoYsstMAYO8l5Pkmbyg1pIbXGxu8y6ySjHlvP4YGfS4aYcqIsHBSJzeqqMLFnh3NbxuFDJLWHkhKZUkRGGFA6kROzim6Ryq2@UmuxYKwqAOn7QAadi1I6tjxQH7PHQoXyl0H6ZDKCqZkssoQCEZUQGj3hYA4BRubuRNO8BRgYhxw6t/Pjy@PcSdIIVwrO9XehtcyUMnQQRmx4WRz0Zz2K@s2NAJbEDpf75ZSaktrB4zg6ZvA3cSeGok8oM9Re7ynesN3kqTBBlorCRJWcC8gnXqHnX5RgYPafkk89IE8pJ/4Ed4Bu7D4feClOWHa9c5DuFR7KNimkaWYg/aabSpZ@bpskpSsfFztqpwcHO2wkMeKgqDAJWYQ6B7QrI///CaPw4FwE14td3iaj0kJrm1twEgmA@g6N@GUdnq4t7ZwKfW51TAwbGMgXDfArYgS1GKoIqES/GmHRJE5Tc7dUygNZI1Ar/JZi8PDDyzQJ700TeKDSL/UymIBQiEmeNkIMVb6FPOHBCg86xaXbCAdQTCtTUlo2lC@d0puUI7Hx0UgdhO/ONjS8xCRk1MiU7BfK8ahtKvepyZ8kfssQkDMwqxFwYTc@QEA2YdJR8G0CoyrGLY9iR8wZHFMYOymaC5vFrMZ9Dg@KxiOUcwMqKjBZWGO28jlFelcwyu4El5fiYc@T48@M/9wOeGQJ7Ge0ZH/gKGzfu84yiL1oqec7bwKKKTXEIFXeySmojpcHBPrOBuwt7KtHwiE6Xe56wPL7iEvH@UKSPI2dpTihYOlneoEhUjrvWTfhkcXKaScMnyRelydNQRBTUa2zt4Ss0QTyMbojhHB6jd5ElXGkdx4@lKWQsX8I6nItdUfLVhCqqCZTPaZBnYZXt1uLV1QYpFlnCZFlBNidQXbBk8WxgO5QJ4@mbR8@AyBwEClOGTCoj5Py83OOJIiMF6XNQlHThSDhhCKEVCAGPEF7RcnDyjkH@tBaHSvFDz3YhVcAHFuyl52ixStJ3iOFkwTY7U4q5Hf1GZuFD4Es7KbPEJi4W736zohAcbdUIf1pWE6cS93M/bWMMjy/xMrIuLdRyq4uD7rxd2vNp0gpg8u0F0LRwfmcXXx@H4XSp45@h1OWVTKpYfFMNWl6tTWx3DHF3ORMwvhXnNxw4@nO7CRdqWrUs4rHkTDomLw3Fo0bo1EguA8vSOlx0quCy6DtzaRkXjnmSLfOEYEnJ/eEblYgNRpWwMoOKip6XkwKNerFLAwMWLxZ4uLzZfxFgRU0uepD0hT1UAsPrUwVnrgwTtwz3FSiSWnkPCT4x8qQnRpR2mcVtlt7kg7QlKhpmJHswxp/DKTkiZjtsnSMrmuGnbUhRcIFKBoZnOawyHlHHOpAR4gs6sIr@il7s4ELLrTg59k48/L0wx1fjyw36ae4n5Cv46HUvsPu2ZzgkXaoG82H3gqxnT10hTRTv6KC9@M5wBXJA8wRMGaCX2Qvuhl5dvnv39h399kp1dUWcFz37vMOeOCvICZUHe0euTByvgfs8OFUi@EjV8bKkFn@igj7sYrpeBAcr@ASSM7IjS50vkiLyociWxg4NoIdtF@rP2OUPYSl7OItt9rKgzR6thhTzEgg9yC3wXSgUku7IsoxdFnZlczTehHJuWtjgr2dpS4usjxwO0qOimvidHocEVjsqpEh2LdQYj9Oy2ylbtifjxh6@t3qntLSoogniTBP/UWHiqW7yQJePP/c4txIOHTi1ikdekXnfyRw07hs2JXnPsP/MkrlF4iNGr2yEdm2lVKstlmq3785rbnlNlmLvzGCbOuAXqoZJ7WN/GCrq5VWrje@bgzoQCKsDX@4P@dbfowElZzrxARNw1Ury2l2ZbIj3CG8R9q60tusYJzAIZlLjhigCfAizmQVKUfwS4hpDRWwvZo3IpCK32IQmZrfLbKyq2lqstd@sA9Ixz1LFC4EK/y8VfKJlqHyRtVVbxFwEyFAaoxcghgWYqv4f)

Next answer must not exceed 4213 bytes.

### Changes

<s>I wrote an interpreter for the newly added language which I added to the TIO (`nameless.hs`).</s> (@Dennis just added the interpreter to TIO, [try it here](https://tio.run/#nameless))

I changed the `somme-fix.py` such that it tries to avoid characters which clash with others (such as **Brain-Flak** etc.) and such that it doesn't need manual fiddling with the last two lines.

### Explanation

This language is basically just **brainfuck** differently encoded (every instruction is 4 characters of `0`s and `1`s), but it extends the instruction set by a few instructions. To no-op all the instructions resulting from intial code I inserted `00 0011 0110` right where the **99** code is which is equivalent to closing `p` (reset pointer) and the instructions `-[` to set the cell to 0 and skip all the remaining code.

Later (after the stones code) follows the closing `]` and the code which is basically this (`a` adds the value of the next instruction to the cell and `p` as above):

```
>a++>a+a+>>aaa++>a+a+>aa+++>>aa++->aaa+->a++>aa+>a++>aa++>>aa+++>->p<a+[>aaaaa<-]>--p[[>+]-p-]>.>.>.>.>.>.>.>.[-]aaaa++a.>..>.>.>.>.>.>.>+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCcAwDEMHEuoEwYuYHHTIrS2B7I/zK4VgjCU9gV895S6tRZiAsYKZ9OupVgJw5dy9ifb9KIxWk@CzJSVmI6u7IbMOc53jzFpvNMzJEBFsHQ)

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 705c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  /op\. /+ #\. bas
00000060: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
00000070: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000080: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000090: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
000000b0: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
000000c0: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
000000d0: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
000000e0: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
000000f0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000100: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000110: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
00000120: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
00000130: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
00000140: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
00000150: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
00000160: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
00000170: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000180: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000190: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
000001a0: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
000001b0: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
000001c0: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
000001d0: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
000001e0: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
000001f0: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000200: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000210: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
00000220: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
00000230: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
00000240: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000250: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000280: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
000002c0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002f0: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000300: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000310: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
00000320: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
00000330: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
00000340: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
00000350: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
00000360: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
00000370: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000380: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000390: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
000003a0: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
000003b0: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
000003c0: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
000003d0: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
000003e0: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
000003f0: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000400: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000410: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
00000420: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
00000430: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
00000440: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
00000450: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000470: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000480: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000490: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
000004a0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
000004b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004d0: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
000004e0: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
000004f0: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000500: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000510: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000520: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22   <>"v"@. @,"F","
00000530: 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22  u","n","c","t","
00000540: 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564  o","i","d"<> red
00000550: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
00000560: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
00000570: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000580: 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  ow up green down
00000590: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
000005a0: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
000005b0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
000005c0: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
000005d0: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77  een down red dow
000005e0: 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  n one yellow dow
000005f0: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000600: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000610: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
00000620: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
00000630: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
00000640: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
00000650: 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77  left one red dow
00000660: 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  n three yellow d
00000670: 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  own yellow down 
00000680: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000690: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20  down red up two 
000006a0: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  green down yello
000006b0: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
000006c0: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075   blue left red u
000006d0: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
000006e0: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
000006f0: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000700: 7565 206c 6566 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030  ue left 00011100
00000710: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000720: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
00000730: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000740: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000750: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
00000760: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
00000770: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030  1000100010000000
00000780: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000790: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000110000100010
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030  0010000010001100
000007b0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007c0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007e0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000800: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000810: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030  0000110000110000
00000820: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030  0110000010011000
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010001000100010
00000840: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031  0010000001001101
00000850: 3131 3030 3030 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131  1100000011001111
00000860: 3030 3031 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030  0001100110000000
00000870: 3130 3031 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030  1001110011110000
00000880: 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  1101110000010000
00000890: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008a0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008b0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008c0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031  0001000110001101
000008d0: 3131 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  1110001000100010
000008e0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031  0000100010100001
000008f0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0000000100010000
00000900: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000910: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000920: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000930: 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 0a2e 4c20 2020  0000100110..L   
00000940: 202e 202e 2020 2020 2020 2020 202a 2f2f   . .         *//
00000950: 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63  /{}]........laoc
00000960: 7261 6843 c2ab e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2  rahC............
00000970: b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000980: e286 a8c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690  ................
00000990: c39f e289 a4e2 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286  ................
000009a0: 90e2 89a5 e286 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2  ................
000009b0: 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692  ................
000009c0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286  ................
000009d0: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3  ................
000009e0: 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286  ................
000009f0: 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000a00: 8692 e286 a8c2 b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a10: e286 a8c2 a1cf 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c  ................
00000a20: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a30: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2  ................
00000a40: 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692  ................
00000a50: e286 a8c2 a1ce b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a60: a1cf 80c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1  ................
00000a70: e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2  ................
00000a80: c2a1 ceb4 c2a1 cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000a90: b2e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1  ................
00000aa0: c2bb 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d  ..++++[-<+++++>]
00000ab0: 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  <[-<++++++<+++++
00000ac0: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b  <+++++>>>]<<<+++
00000ad0: 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d  ++++.>-.>---.<<-
00000ae0: 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d  ----.++++++++.--
00000af0: 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e  ---.>--.>---.<+.
00000b00: 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928  >>>((((((((((()(
00000b10: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28  )()){}){}){}){}(
00000b20: 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929  )){})((()()()())
00000b30: 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d  {}){})[(([][]){}
00000b40: 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29  ){}()])([]()){})
00000b50: 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28  []())(([[][]()](
00000b60: 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29  []()((((([][][])
00000b70: 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d  ){}{})[]){})))[]
00000b80: 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 2821  ())({ -}_=")";(!
00000b90: 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574 2062  )=seq;main|let b
00000ba0: 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222  !_=""=putStr$(""
00000bb0: 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22  !"snrettaPgnaB+"
00000bc0: 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b 7361 4828  )++init"lleksaH(
00000bd0: 227b 2d0a 2f2f 4848 542d 224e 5562 3460  "{-.//HHT-"NUb4`
00000be0: 424a 4a6e 644f 2d7d 2d2d 2973 2a2f 2fe2  BJJndO-}--)s*//.
00000bf0: 8899 5341 564e 4143 efbd 90f0 9f92 ac69  ..SAVNAC.......i
00000c00: 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e a1f0 9f98 ad45  jome...........E
00000c10: 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f 6ef0 9f98 b2e2  motinomicon.....
00000c20: 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 402c 6b61 2238 392d  ........@,ka"89-
00000c30: 6567 6e75 6665 6e55 7373 7373 7361 6161  egnufenUsssssaaa
00000c40: 6161 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 7061 6565  aaeeeeeeeeeepaee
00000c50: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6369 7361 6565 6565  eeeeeeeecisaeeee
00000c60: 6565 656a 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565  eeejiiiiiiiijeee
00000c70: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 656a  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeej
00000c80: 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565  iiiiiiiiiiiiijee
00000c90: 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 696a 6969 6969  eeeeeejiiiijiiii
00000ca0: 6969 6969 6969 696a 22                   iiiiiiij"
```

Answer (score 4):

## 41. [evil](https://esolangs.org/wiki/evil), 3275 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
.L    . .         *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-"NUb4`BJJndO-}--)s*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijzaeeeaeeaewuuuweeeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbcttGls/CL8xLC1RMQCQIUbJliSIZ3W1nbUtjKbHXFM2AQJOEBAIcXEjJiqZSO1WpnaqtTWoeUrv7sKlU7W7tZfZhUpOHqc2@eN6Tf9APzPyB95zuxoUX2U5mYRHsPvc@fbr7HBBuG0Hv9esc2bIsYhDaNaKuazwkoQe9gedcdB0vJCENQtIzfJcGAWlfkMc23X1JT8@8tpQjO57jGIOAEnnHs6hMDNci8pbfjfrUDQOZBNQMbc8NSMfzSZuGIfUJPR9Q36auSSXJNEJSJybwSo5LtIA12a3U7pAc2aadyO1SbX1FCr3I7JGBb4NgCVTbHXLhRcRA22OFRdI3zigJIp/iKPqeZXcuCFhQGlyQwCNhD/SFPXoBLJTYrulEFrWggUDi2O6ZRM2eRzSXyAtlGUzjvBnoMkItLxiHriA08Pp9qnXsc8RJg4uw57kr49CY455vBEFFCn2imRYZPR2SKnMC4iXp4dbjex9u3dtrPXi8u/esVpa2//p476gmLygjExgYqSpL4BrmXeIYbjcyulRRL6U5pkLOkYVxKSWyUC6SBSYJphFmVY5pn0Sua7tdwkZ8a1maa0NcgB422roXhYMolObA1i3tOTG0l6RKOBDGzBuaYwphzBuX5WLxSv7Ep8M6TrYZUivWNQunuY40B9M5T8z@IJVIYjy5detGHPBu4OS50hzX8NT3YCicsETu03Mr6g8qgD0/t0g8lo4tzU04GZyrTLisUFbVxEkaOfl4QcF45ULUk48xbpjP6nFYXmFg9sJwEFR0vWuHvahdMr2@fuxfPAgPXAgwqof@hR16cZtSvW8EsCz0kW8MYGEEICGeTyLj4pOJzExgbSnF7QLC6ltE8yOXLZks8gijDgj8CJas7g1CncUhv5f89hRDvVoH8jhoGUfHDnrshqtnkn4HqBmVqYWmqbdtV4fv2cbswPZheoaTsIh@0pil4CO7D/RDu59sC9AuhRAFdd2iQ92NHIcs12@VMTxwXgQ6K@Og/QFuQEOqobldtO@ceO1TATS5XM3LwpgKEFnSJ4BZwcm@tBaPqZ1AmC867bY9NaR0N5vgYizQ5vZ8QkLDdnABFlbWs/z7EC67B0dk5@AR6dgOzUwY35GyxPc8Z8acdj2HTWvgm3F7lvM/dLMDHFywDtG0ILRq62vQiATBzWO8O@WZu1o/7Ng63kBCDLxZwupbJCTg1SkZbd@w3U5kniUiYkDammI69t8y6NC/YdBMptZxjHF9PQP0bWPrviH0EW1rjBF2Wpl/TQm9bwRn1HHYIgZRrDNF9JLxv5zBTvveqT05/QzI77OmXagsbAPk0MDT2g3G9WvPsrjplV4o4EIrFHChmfAVLzBzMEgXluhkGff6Xmi7Xt82PRc3vPOB54fk8cHuXutw6/h@7UTWo8DXHbutuyCyBUd75NDgREaJCEnGl4gZ65ROp409Y747m@E7i0@LNWta0ih55wh/Q@RsObY5vk8bCNHhOKH@wKdwn7Vb/zwyrJ9ixy9SvimZ6@uxnPV1HRICGl7gfYZuNO6n6E74pmQGF/22BwMn2YXb91xPnF3tDn5K9JyzzjoCGDXLHIFq7CiE/o@3Noi5pm2F05sGsSTe00PIQWmo@9ShRkAFdPpUpoPwJ9kyuMlx@5gDerYVC@uIftKY4mCp51jEdRHC77NizXAGvZk7qUCQku1isgWp6NhWsPX4o62jOHk52vro8daOzBNg@fHB8V6F7Bju0AhIP4ICo01ZfgPJnuOZhuNAhh4mmZT10rD7RkkkVLanc079fQiCrErX6IP/oUyJQbHNMUK37ABGENmOlcISrqkddGjj7ntqDA04jB1wz8AIe2KjARxhN84lsQywQ/InbhWWbZ3l6PV8UgVgNo01kIlJozegrpJHirxa8qlhKWqF8SsmljWebymmWq@tLGM5xXvV8vJd7Jmw2YUgI1@t31rIUwdKr07@Vu6SU11t5IvUtWr5PCSusUVVndlS1dGuE/fEPWTJagWbeVaBiexVMMgnbgMSVmJDqsvS1Plm4/jBQRPpH9PzEIq8YAR1HJs3tIaemxQmDhNoVl7Uyysr7/PmYnlFLy9VeKdwe0lVee1RQmG5XJyfY0@WMENHUz8JQFo@0F/oBC49n/EtM6SSBAZWZ3A46blc6mlesb1@PcTg1xe1S00jud6T@WfaJjl80fvlL59tbi7tkqVduTfkwOc9Unh2h8iP5h8R6sAEPDrYIUcHu5T6@wtXBbgai7oO034iEb1AcvAFBzbFuIGCRsEJxNKRgIM9U19Y0GHrUFmJs1GpVvN7B/t5kqvXT6RyAcSQqevgRNIXyc@6XfNe3/7oZ8@fb3ieJzvePXnj/drSe0fz5TIAqixFl3IW7eCufIQZOL90fUvK2R1AkFbLHDhRgB9ddyTSUdSNrCpdt4GU171VExIb26vrupmRWiiAXF2nEgRZmDUXVENo2Z0EdFJKtR5sf7DTamWN02BxhCb9oH0QM0pQnNsu1Kh8OpUjVV/UBcjus/MeDCoxozaguimNfDuk@uKivnGlL15VpTohw9FTuNjt6Qg7ox/feDpKr0RY/JV8Z1vjnTH4DZB3BD0dzQI@TWy7AfX0ZhS/pPX1dcI/aRNbw2p9Ca5yGf@kISEQUmnSW4yvuxcr2rBKNtHluRf3hlMhu1mUt@UW5ELAsykBYFhttORmpsCpJ8KKS59sVpGmnqtmk/s6eTFcuAfGoB2MUL67rtGuG3Xotkxa0wtlyGKAkW7mOCjD4x/LrWGOoMilcrUukTde1XoZPXFvYcgJc5vFsWszl5FsGdHP5RZjSDluvLIDCV07ZQXe@eGYnrdIGr8yUgf0CNw/ltmMD2Az91bZMPVDGSYP5nJfLsoRfFz4mPAJ4ePBx4aPJVfrxIcd2fJGLglHHus4tIPHAyUXUBV4IxINSBeqU5dTzQQiG0DCHoBYx7e7vZBJFPRZXtZuOxHlqibksEZG/TtQv8HydxKS8KUS2Uh@tO3oA7BlprtmC/iLPMeWO4s/HoTlsRbes70sxbvQT9NNy8ngyjfIL79J4tJbNL6D3hhTTu/JV7Y19UkIhA85cZn3yimvIEtxWZ4MyY/@jhXFKmeMrzzF8xP1iaFKpYe4P5TgX3xh/nN51bz@@3/603f/9uoPjuGZvtHbefVf119@8yr5d/13f3P92b9//zu4/fEruKWw68@@AMiv/@X6y@@uP/sNu39x/et/xTbD//ArbIo/xpz2fvg00xOwV1//8atXXyfd738/g5HRfTvO9cNnSP0tiGRqx8UIkk/BmC@/iQl@@NWrbwUJ9L7/Xdr@4VNoAyH7G2syAUD8e6YwhnPYtzj4L7979fWr/2GZpVbFr0K9WY2bhWrmXq8DpioQhVJdgz9NK1WrGl6lQozg3boW44G0XlfSS8V/6uVV8sd7MSbBNRSl0Ww0Y5qmCl2OZN@ARTQgGJyJRgBwAA2jQlpVUF8S7apVk1V5Q5lXawH9xQbme584FAq@eUDINSgcj0J/QZHleTlwfRqGxmHXNbYLsloo2K4dyo5DzwLjviJfapKu379/rMmPP2zf/nj7gw9c60C70jQ1gPC8/tt/5DXmn/73iz9/9Zvf2qden2Lj@p@//vNX//Df2QdM0P/m@vP/vP78t9ef/8dm8cyQ1@KT1f0wwMvAiybXINM27SDundriOqVTV4IbJ2DgLO70JUoz8G8URdGIUaH2M/4Fiav8uuN7ffLSsduEJ8qLkkiYsQ5ZvS11ao7Rb1sGcSustnSLeb@d1JaSVWvn8RHjyXmng598oaPkS@xZCVRLebXQzqco3s6XTj3IzDvKvopl6z5UAw1esRbzvMKCBn/oDI3sb1z5piqZNdPrQ7kZBF77VFkv7u7tP9w63tstao@2nrWebj84PkJY69Heo9bDvY/2HhaXVF7lKXxEpfbqbeqiPsUsxbIUSy2YpQ7UNj1FLbbzmzoM0aKMCsYahL49UPK1vKq@zpHdgyPNsc8oOV9bJX2IpL4BBXs/cowQf4qc@B0Tij78BTD50XPk@WcB6VGfFrEOHtmOw2BYvYNTHRRfBO/7Pv5w1o66ARcCtJZHAzfPRQgJ@Dsl1IZto@1cEBdr5dCDqjmEsgg40t8yGapHnQEoDHuCAhWEPTsgRhtGaLBf/IrECM5In8a/XJrofyjhiddhKQp89S9EnQ5AlwswewYsJkgXpTh8gotAYrHFnxZ5TiACjAwMP7QNR5KYJZkHFjyyQD/pVKQ5GFXXN/qkRjpxsPVp3/MvANJ4DKY0F1fv3FlZFdDG8p3VCnwKYIYieNUm0Iq2ZFEnaUs@7dr401gABJf5B4f5Clk6hyOqSPJHDzKdnWess7S0v1@U5vK72EXdSHeYtncfxG0g2op5mITtDMt2zHIldRyjy5Xv7ANw33ACpDjIdp5nO0fZzmHSuZIkLJOp73u@0g@6KvMcRntH3nvy5OBJhVwC@Aq@kjHP@1eyKs3BDJXouR0qZZUL6dKwhRPRwucoCkrCBhgpPJwIaKDHmk32yyojgQjAYVWEHXkoHswoxPCKXF63W0JIHhRPyCGFGikjNIx8l8mbMGeET6DQHMcDYyaslOZ69iyoEKcAtlolayopEMeTpCd7944wgHCW@Pzi9LH7NrvDtPKZ4qHAJ7eJfPe3Hu4j72U8xwoXwuZBLZIc2XoIqB2O2hlH7TyMw0fh6lLULqK2OWp7HLWNKBZoQtexHwlV95HpMFWVYHYQw4JYaEowu4jZfZAqSjDb9yURSLAZes6Q/Qji99eY1/1@EcBdGPkYsryKbsaNKbDdIDRckypICjsJcgEbcMRua/j9Jpv4MRjtNpOJElpmWIGKQCBrz5rp7a2jPZzSRjyDMF9FEvd2497hGO4wi4uhGdpYAkY5bIOtOGa5/UcNbo2ukzXyHllrMvPYUonhcHRyF3AIEDFncbIaWWEu4kNnAsFBRZLVJM3hI1gkw3MLBC1BEw9M9CJszjhs5EIKlJyuKvTr1JKM3ICGCREKsOEA8KkZipVJDNOEkxAXqFBZqE0IjW25BcbAQd7pSNJcdlBLiS197K6ybjzKieU8Odi5ZLgJB@riQYHIjJ4yI4tXOLd1Mi5UcksYOaUpUWQEAYUDKRa7/Cap3OobpcY71poCoJbnt8CpGLUT6yPBAXs0cChfKbRbJD2ou9kSiykAYRmhwSMe1gBgVO5uJM16gJFByLFDKzu@LP69GB1jhfB0bxd6m1wJQ8dBxKaHxVFHxrOY7@wYUHHshCD@MhVSWVo@Z4dM1gbupGDcSUWG@otd5TnWmzwVxIgiUdjI4jMB@YRr1KzrMgyMnlPyyWekMeW0/8AO8I3dhUNvjSlLj1cu8p3CI95GxTSNLcSfNFPJ0s9M0/QUJeNiZ@3M4GDn7RQGPFQWBgGrMIfAdgXk/39hNHmci4Aa8@u7RFRySM1ya2YCQTCfwXG/TKLT1cW9M4XPrM6ZAQNjmYFhPgVszxYjFUEVixdjjLukDkrudiopQKvFaoX/YkxWHhj5ZoGdWSJvFJrGfipTEAoRsbPGyMGKt9DHHDihfuvUNFtBD@oJBapuy8bShXM6s3IEdj46iYOwnfrGxpejhIwKmZGdAnlWtQ2lXnm1teINWGIS@GYZYi4IZ2dIiAZMMkq@DSBU5djlCezYeYMjCiIHZTNBi/i1nM2hQfFExHIOYGVFRgMrjGZWxzivSuaZ3cCScDznHBn@7PjPPZ9nhsBeRHsmB77Gxo37PKPoipZKXvA2sKhiUxxAxR2vkspYaXB0yGzg7sKeSjQ8opPlniUsTq64WLw3EOnj2FmaEQqWTpc3KBKV4651Ez5enJxm2vBp8mVp@jQUEQX1Glt7@GqOHw3CG2I4g8foXWYJV1LH8WNpBhnLl7AO52LXlGw1oYpqAuVzGuRZWme7tXgZt0byeZYwWZafzglUFyxZHPVshzJhPH1z6QiIzJ6vMGXIpDJCzs/LPZ4oMlKQvgBFSRuOhDOGEFqBEPAI4RUtB8dvIWRPa3Go5D907T6kCvjAgr17HS6XSfIqM5ws2GZnSj6zo9/ILHwIfEknYZbYxEXiFXRWFIKjrQrhT8sq4lTifu4mbYzhySVeRNaVpUpmdXHQnbdLezFLWg5Mvr0EmpbO7@zjW@wwnDZ1vBFKXV1LpYrFN9Og1fXK1HbHEHdXUwGTW3F2w4GjP7ObcKGmVUkjHkvOuGPy0lA8aoROhWQysDStw0WnCi6LvjOXlnLhmKfZUk8IloTcG7xRidhgVAkrM6io6HkxLtCoG/Wpb8DixQIPlzf7nwqsqMlED5K@tAeKb7hdquDMFWHiVuG@BkVSI@shwSdGHvfEiJIus7jJ0ptskDZERcOMZA/G@HM4JUPEbIetc2xFM/ysDSn0L1BJz3Ath1XGY@pYBzJCfIUHVtFf0Ys9XGiZFSdH7pmLvyhm@Cp8uUE/yf2EfAUfvR74dtd2DYckS9VgPmxfkM30qSukieItHrQX30UuQQ5onoEpPfQye3He0Murd@/evqPfXiuvr4nzomOft9gTZwU5ofJg794ViePWcJ8Hp0oEH6k6bprU4o9Y0IddTNfz4GAFn0ByRnZkqYt5kkc@FNnQ2KEB9LDtQv0Z9flDWMoezmKbvYRos0erAcW8BEIPcgt8WwqFJDuyLGOXhV3RHI83oZybFtT4C1zayjLrI4eD9KioIn7JxyGB1Y4KKZJdCTTG4zTsZsKW7sm4sQfvrd8prCyraII408R/gJh6qhs/0OXjzzzOLQUDB06t/ImbZ953UgdN@oZNSdYz7P/UpG6R@IjRK1uBXVkrVCrLhcrtu4tav7ghS5E7MtimDvilsmFS@9QbBIp6edVo4nvsoA4EwurA/zQQ8K2/Q31KRjrxAONz1Ur8Ol@RbIn3E28R9g62tu8YZzAIZlLthigCfACzmQZKXvwS0jcGithezAqRSUlusAmNzW4W2VhVtbFcab5ZB6RjrqWKVwYV/l81@ETLUPkia6OyjLkIkKE0Ri9ADAswVf0/)

Next answer must not exceed 4257 bytes.

### Changes

I modified the incorrect output check to be case-insensitive so that it matches the rules and so we don't have to edit the language name in the list if we need to play with case for things like alphuck and evil.

The evil code was added at the end of the program, immediately after the alphuck code. It contains no j's, p's, or s's, so it didn't cause any adverse effects with alphuck.

### Explanation

evil operates only on lowercase letters. The most useful letters to know for debugging are *f*, *b*, *m*, *j*, *x*, *w*.

- f: skip forward to next marker
- b: skip backward to next marker
- m: marker character for default marking mode
- j: marker character for secondary marking mode
- x: toggle marking modes
- w: output the value of the accumulator as ascii

Conveniently, evil doesn't hit any *w* that I didn't want it to. It hits an *x* early on, and the low number of *j* means it jumps into "ijome" near the end of the file pretty quickly. From there, it slides through alphuck, which does all sorts of nonsense to evil's data structures, and then it resets the accumulator and does it's thing.

Quick breakdown of the code:

- `z` - reset *A* to 0
- `aeeeaeeaew` - get ascii value for "L" into *A*, output
- `uuuw` - decrements *A*'s value to "I", output
- `eeeeeaaaak` - change *A*'s value to "e", store in *P*
- `eeaaaaw` - change *A*'s value to "v", output
- `vw` - swap *A* and *P*, output

This could potentially be golfed down a tad. There's a chance that some of the data structures have useful values in them when we get to the end of the alphuck code, but (1) I was tracing this by hand for the most part, and did not feel like figuring all of that out or tracking down a worthwhile evil editor, (2) relying on stuff like that can be a nightmare for maintainability, so it's probably better for sanity reasons to just reset our values and work from scratch. I've had some success interleaving evil and alphuck in the past. Threw together some quick notes about how I think that could be done here but I didn't have time to test it. Is someone working on a future answer wants those just ping me here or in the chat.

Also, I ended up not needed this, but you can at least put an *x*, maybe an *xf* between `[*` on the first line, which would jet you jump from the first line to the first lowercase *j*. Currently we're using the *x* in `exe` and the f in `define`, which works, but depending on where future languages get added an earlier jump might be useful.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 705c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  /op\. /+ #\. bas
00000060: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
00000070: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000080: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000090: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
000000b0: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
000000c0: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
000000d0: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
000000e0: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
000000f0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000100: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000110: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
00000120: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
00000130: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
00000140: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
00000150: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
00000160: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
00000170: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000180: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000190: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
000001a0: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
000001b0: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
000001c0: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
000001d0: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
000001e0: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
000001f0: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000200: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000210: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
00000220: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
00000230: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
00000240: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000250: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000280: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
000002c0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002f0: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000300: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000310: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
00000320: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
00000330: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
00000340: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
00000350: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
00000360: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
00000370: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000380: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000390: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
000003a0: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
000003b0: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
000003c0: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
000003d0: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
000003e0: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
000003f0: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000400: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000410: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
00000420: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
00000430: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
00000440: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
00000450: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000470: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000480: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000490: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
000004a0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
000004b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004d0: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
000004e0: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
000004f0: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000500: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000510: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000520: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22   <>"v"@. @,"F","
00000530: 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22  u","n","c","t","
00000540: 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564  o","i","d"<> red
00000550: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
00000560: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
00000570: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000580: 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  ow up green down
00000590: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
000005a0: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
000005b0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
000005c0: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
000005d0: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77  een down red dow
000005e0: 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  n one yellow dow
000005f0: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000600: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000610: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
00000620: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
00000630: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
00000640: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
00000650: 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77  left one red dow
00000660: 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  n three yellow d
00000670: 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  own yellow down 
00000680: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000690: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20  down red up two 
000006a0: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  green down yello
000006b0: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
000006c0: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075   blue left red u
000006d0: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
000006e0: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
000006f0: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000700: 7565 206c 6566 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030  ue left 00011100
00000710: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000720: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
00000730: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000740: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000750: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
00000760: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
00000770: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030  1000100010000000
00000780: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000790: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000110000100010
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030  0010000010001100
000007b0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007c0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007e0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000800: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000810: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030  0000110000110000
00000820: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030  0110000010011000
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010001000100010
00000840: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031  0010000001001101
00000850: 3131 3030 3030 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131  1100000011001111
00000860: 3030 3031 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030  0001100110000000
00000870: 3130 3031 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030  1001110011110000
00000880: 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  1101110000010000
00000890: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008a0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008b0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008c0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031  0001000110001101
000008d0: 3131 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  1110001000100010
000008e0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031  0000100010100001
000008f0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0000000100010000
00000900: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000910: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000920: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000930: 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 0a2e 4c20 2020  0000100110..L   
00000940: 202e 202e 2020 2020 2020 2020 202a 2f2f   . .         *//
00000950: 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63  /{}]........laoc
00000960: 7261 6843 c2ab e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2  rahC............
00000970: b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000980: e286 a8c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690  ................
00000990: c39f e289 a4e2 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286  ................
000009a0: 90e2 89a5 e286 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2  ................
000009b0: 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692  ................
000009c0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286  ................
000009d0: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3  ................
000009e0: 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286  ................
000009f0: 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000a00: 8692 e286 a8c2 b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a10: e286 a8c2 a1cf 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c  ................
00000a20: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a30: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2  ................
00000a40: 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692  ................
00000a50: e286 a8c2 a1ce b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a60: a1cf 80c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1  ................
00000a70: e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2  ................
00000a80: c2a1 ceb4 c2a1 cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000a90: b2e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1  ................
00000aa0: c2bb 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d  ..++++[-<+++++>]
00000ab0: 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  <[-<++++++<+++++
00000ac0: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b  <+++++>>>]<<<+++
00000ad0: 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d  ++++.>-.>---.<<-
00000ae0: 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d  ----.++++++++.--
00000af0: 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e  ---.>--.>---.<+.
00000b00: 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928  >>>((((((((((()(
00000b10: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28  )()){}){}){}){}(
00000b20: 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929  )){})((()()()())
00000b30: 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d  {}){})[(([][]){}
00000b40: 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29  ){}()])([]()){})
00000b50: 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28  []())(([[][]()](
00000b60: 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29  []()((((([][][])
00000b70: 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d  ){}{})[]){})))[]
00000b80: 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 2821  ())({ -}_=")";(!
00000b90: 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574 2062  )=seq;main|let b
00000ba0: 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222  !_=""=putStr$(""
00000bb0: 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22  !"snrettaPgnaB+"
00000bc0: 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b 7361 4828  )++init"lleksaH(
00000bd0: 227b 2d0a 2f2f 4848 542d 224e 5562 3460  "{-.//HHT-"NUb4`
00000be0: 424a 4a6e 644f 2d7d 2d2d 2973 2a2f 2fe2  BJJndO-}--)s*//.
00000bf0: 8899 5341 564e 4143 efbd 90f0 9f92 ac69  ..SAVNAC.......i
00000c00: 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e a1f0 9f98 ad45  jome...........E
00000c10: 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f 6ef0 9f98 b2e2  motinomicon.....
00000c20: 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 402c 6b61 2238 392d  ........@,ka"89-
00000c30: 6567 6e75 6665 6e55 7373 7373 7361 6161  egnufenUsssssaaa
00000c40: 6161 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 7061 6565  aaeeeeeeeeeepaee
00000c50: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6369 7361 6565 6565  eeeeeeeecisaeeee
00000c60: 6565 656a 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565  eeejiiiiiiiijeee
00000c70: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 656a  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeej
00000c80: 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565  iiiiiiiiiiiiijee
00000c90: 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 696a 6969 6969  eeeeeejiiiijiiii
00000ca0: 6969 6969 6969 696a 7a61 6565 6561 6565  iiiiiiijzaeeeaee
00000cb0: 6165 7775 7575 7765 6565 6565 6161 6161  aewuuuweeeeeaaaa
00000cc0: 6b65 6561 6161 6177 7677 22              keeaaaawvw"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are printing "LIve" as opposed to "live"?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I think it's just easier that way

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Yeah, I started with capital, but using the [weave function](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil#Weaving) after printing "I" got me closer to the lowercase values sooner, so it saved a couple bytes to switch to those.

Answer (score 4):

## 43. braille, 3420 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
.L    . .         *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>]((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-"NUb4`BJJndO-}--)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijzaeeeaeeaewuuuweeeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbctvIlc/CL@SlBWpMQCQIUbJliSYZ3W3P2pZieWyvKZoDAk0SEggwuJCSNUpNbapcm6qtTCoPs5eHHc/Wbmov2a3KVOZha2dfnPeZf9APJH/gPae7ceFFtmeyIAl097n26dPd5wBg2wh6b97kyKZlEYPQrhF1XeMeCT2oDTznrOt4IQlpEJKe4bs0CEj7jDyw6c4LenzitaUc2fYcxxgElMjbnkVlYrgWkTf9btSnbhjIJKBmaHtuQDqeT9o0DKlP6OmA@jZ1TSpJphGSOjGBVnJcogWsyE6ldofkyBbtRG6XausrUuhFZo8MfBsYSyDa7pAzLyIG6h4LLJK@cUJJEPkUe9H3LLtzRkCD0uCMBB4JeyAv7NEzIKHEdk0nsqgFBWwkju2eSNTseURzibxQlkE1TptpXcZWywvGW1ewNfD6fap17NNx2HWEPS4NjNDsSdLgLOx57sps5Nu@EQQVKfSJZlpk9GRIqsw2CJeke5sPbn@0eXu3dffBzu7TWlna@stHu4c1eUEZmUDAUFVZAosxoxPHcLuR0aWKei7NMRFyjiyMcymRhXKRLDBOMLow2HKM@zByXdvtEmaIa8vSXBvcBeQwI9S9KBxEoTQHum5qz4ihvSBVwhuhu7ygOaZgxgxxXi4WL@RPfDqsow@YIbViWbNgmutIczDK88TsD1KOJIaTa9euhAHtLRxTV5rjEp74HnSFI5bIHXpqRf1BBaCnpxaJ@9KxpbkJI4NxlQmTFcqqmhhJI0cfLyjoxpyJevQxuhOzWT321gv0114YDoKKrnftsBe1S6bX1x/5Z3fDfRf8juqhf2aHXlymVO8bAcwWfeQbA5gvgRSPJpF3ZCJbfYtofuSyuSJngIfoV4DgRzBXdW8Q6szT@Lnkt6cI6tU6oMduySg6dtBjJ5w2k/jbgM2wTC00Tb1tuzpcZyuzDeuG6RlOQiLqSWGWgMd2H/CHdj9ZD6BcCmGc67pFh7obOQ5Zrl8rowOg5QU4y2O//SGuPEOqobpd1O@UeO1j0WhyvpqXbWMigGVJn2jMMk4WpLW4T@2khdmi027bU11Kl7EJKkYCZa7PJyQ0bAenWGFlPUu/Bw6xs39Itvfvk47t0MyA8aUoi3zbc2aMaddz2LAGvhmXZxn/IzfbwcEZqxBNC0Krtr4GhUggXN3Hm1OWuan1w46t4wk4xI1Xc1h9B4ekeXWKR9s3bLcTmScJi7ghLU0RPfLf0enQv6LTjKfWcYxxeT0D5G1h6Y4h5BFtc4wQ1lKZX6aY3jGCE@o4bBIDK1aZQnrB6F/MIKd979ieHH7WyM@zhl2ILGxBy4GB27QbjMvXnmZh0zO9UMCJVijgRDPhEk8wczBIJ5aoZAl3@15ou17fNj0XOMAC7vkhebC/s9s62Hx0p3Yk61Hg647d1l1g2YI9PXJocCQjR2xJ@pewGauUjqeVPWG2O5lhO4sPizVrWFIveW8Pf4vnbDq2Ob5OG9iiw4ZB/YFP4Txrtf5JZFg/RI@fpnRTPNfXYz7r6zps@TQ8w/MM2ajcD5Gd0E3xDM76bQ86TrITt@@5nti72h38legpJ521BTBsFjIC1thWCPXvr20QU03rCvszDWJOvKaHEHzSUPepQ42AitbpXZkOwh@ky@Aqw@1hlOfZVsysI@pJYYqCBZdjHtfFFn6e5WuGM@jNXEkFgJRsF8MpCDbHloLNB483D4EqnZ2m4Q6NgE3gWfPRNfpgPkgv4qZYZAzQLTsABSLbsdK2hGpqARzauHgeG0MD9lIHegexd0@sEwAj7DQVdgAJRhMiUofNmF8Z2VDrwJpi6I9LvQBXNXad4YuZBZOhzNovHIdmTQrV@CrQJRY2dkj@yK3CSlBngX09n6QOGIJjPmVipOkNqKvkESOvlnxqWIpaYfSKiSmS51uKqdZrK8uYmvFatbx8E2smrJ8h8MhX69cW8tSBNK6Tv5Y751gXt/JF6lq1fB6i3Vijqs50qeqo15F75B6wCLeCxTzL5kTIKwjkI7cBUS6xIT5mse18s/Ho7n4T8R/Q0xASxmAEOWE/giQTtaGnJoXQHqNulpPUyysrP@bFxfKKXl6q8Erh@pKq8oSlhMxyuTiox5osYViPqn4SALd8oD/XCRx6PmNbpkglicsx04Ph03O51NI8@3vzZojzSV/UzjWN5HoP559qG@Tgee9nP3u6sbG0Q5Z25N6QNz7rkcLTG0S@P3@fUAcG4P7@Njnc36HU31u4KMDRWNR1GPzLVy8vv3z5PucjiegFkoMLRAsUvR7yJQWHGhNWAkPhmfrCgg7rlsoyqFuVajW/u7@XJ7l6/UgqF0AgmTr2jyR9kfyo2zVv9@3HP3r27JbnebLj3ZZv/bi29MHhfLkMDVWWH0g5i3ZwSzjE8J8fur4p5ewOAEirZQ6cKMCfrjsS6SjqrawoXbcBlWfbVROiKtur67qZ4VooAF9dpxK4Y5hVF0SDE9qdpOmolErd3/pwu9XKKqfB1A5N@mF7PyaUSB@WLUiB@cArh6q@qIsmu8@CDVCoxJS6BalVaeTbIdUXF/VbF/riRVWqEzIcPYGDnZ6MsDL6/oUno/RImMWX5JotjVfG2q9oec@mJ6NZjU8S3a4APbkaxA9pfX2d8F9axNKwWl@Co1zGrzQkBFwqjbiL8XHzbEUbVskGmjz3/PZwymU3ivKW3IJADGg2JGgYVhstuZnJruoJs@LSJxtVxKnnqtnMok6eDxdugzKoB0OUb65rtOtGHbolk9b0RBkyH2CoGznelKHxH8mtYY4gy6VytS6Rtx7VehktcXthyBFzG8WxYyOX4WwZ0U/kFiNIKa48sh0JXTslBdr54Zicd3AaPzJcB/QQzD8WVo13YCP3Tt4w9EMZBg/Gck8uyhH8XPiZ8Avh58HPhp8lV@vEh7Xb8kYuCUceqzi0gxsJJWeww3ojEg1IF1Jjl2PNbEQyaAl70MQqvt3thYyjwM/SsnLbiSgXNcGHFTLi3wP7LZq/F5OELuXIevK9dUcbgC4zzTWbwZ9lOTbdmf9xJyyPlfCcrWUx3gd/Gm@aTwZWvoJ/@W0cl94h8T3kxpByek4u2dLUL0EQNuTIZV4rp7QCLYVlaTIo3/saC4pFzuhfeYrmB8oTXZVK93B9KMEnPjBSOr9oXv7yH/74zW9e/7djeKZv9LZf/8fl51@9Tj6Xf/NXly//9dvfwekPX8Apbbt8@Sto@cU/X37@zeXLX7Pzry5/8S9YZvDvfo5F8WXEae27TzM10fb6yz988frLpPrt72cQMryvx6m@e4nYXwNLJnacjUD5FJT5/KsY4bufv/5aoEDt29@l5e8@hTIgsu9YkTEA5N8zgXE7b/saO//5N6@/fP0/hYbGwlCtipdCvVmNi4Vq5lyvA6QqAIVSXYOvppWqVQ2PUiEG8Gpdi@GACpRKeqj4Uc8vki@vxZAE1lCURrPRjHGaKlQ5kF0BimAAsHbGGhuAAnAYFuKqAvucaBetmqzKt5R5tRbQn97CmO8Th4akPQ8AuQaZ62HoLyiyPC8Hrk/D0DjousZWQVYLBdu1QxkyspPAuKPI55qk63fuPNLkBx@1r3@89eGHrrWvXWia2tCa1fpR4whORzqc9KOGDqdqHT@8zJrZJf4cHTV11oRgLB4dlfRmAN5@@dd/f7j5@MHm9h//91d/@uLXv7WPvT7FwuU/fvmnL/7uP7M3y6D@1eVn/3752W8vP/u3jeKJIa/FG7X7UYCHgQdNjkGmbNpBXDu2xXFMp44ENo7AmrOw4xfIzcDvKIqiEcNC6Sf8AnHw5atPL199fvnqby9f/fLyn@D7G/y@@i/5Tcf3@uSFY7cJj8cXJRGXY7qzel3q1Byj37YM4lZYsusW8347SXYlq9bO423Uo9NOB3/5QkfJl9j9IEjf8mqhnU9BvJwvHXuQAHSUPRXz6D1IOho8hS7mecoHBX5jHQrZJ3VQFfcH8k1VMmum14dMOAi89rGyXtzZ3bu3@Wh3p6jd33zaerJ199EhtrXu795v3dt9vHuvuKTyBFThfSu1V69TFyUrZinmpVhqwSx1IJnqKWqxnd/QobMWZVjQ6yD07YGSr@VV9U2O7Owfao59Qsnp2irpg9v2DYfQfuQYIT5xnXhcC/koPuhMnu2OPP8kID3q0yKm6CPbcVgb3lgA8zrIvgjj4Pv4ILAddQPOBHAtjwZunrMQHPBxLCSjbaPtnBEX0/jQg4Q@hDwMKNJHtgzUo84ABIY9gYECwp4dEKMNPTTYE8wiMYIT0qfxA1oTR8INA@J1WEwEl/6ZuIUAjS5nYPYMmLkQn0qxIwVngcS8jN8b85xAuBoZGH5oG44kMU0y91K4j4F80qlIc9Crrm/0SY10Yrfr077nn0FL4wGo0lxcvXFjZVW0NpZvrFbgVwA1FEGrNgFXlCWLOklZ8mnXxkd9ASCc5@8e5Ctk6RT2xCLJH97NVLafssrS0t5eUZrL72AVZSPeQVreuRuXAWkzpmEctjIkWzHJhdRxjC4Xvr0HjXuGEyDGfrbyLFs5zFYOksqFJGFeTn3f85V@0FWZ5dDbO/Luw4f7DyvkHJov4JL0ed6/kFVpDkaoRE/tUCmrnEmXhi0ciBbe4lGQExZASWHhhEEDLdZssifFDAU8ALtVEXrkIVsxoxDdK3L5jQJLMMmD4Ak@pFAjZWwNI99l/CbUGeHNMVTH8UCZCS2luZ49q1WwUwBarZI1lRSI40nSw93bh@hAOEp8fHH42HmLnWFY@UhxV@CD20S6O5v39pD2PB5jhTNh46AWSY5s3gPQNgdtj4O278Xuo3BxKWgHQVsctDUO2kIQczQh65EfCVF3kOggFZVAthHCnFhISiA7CNm5mwpKIFt3JOFIsBh6zpA98vH7a8zqfr8IzV3o@RiwvIpmxoUpsN0gNFyTKogKKwlSARlQxGZr@P0mG/ixNtptJgMlpMzQAgUBQ1aeNdJbm4e7OKSNeARhvIokru3EtYMx2EEWFrdmcGMO6OWwDLZin@X6Hza4NrpO1sgHZK3J1GNTJW6HTZSbgLcAEjMWR6uRFWYi3nXGEAxUJFlJ0hzeHUY03LeA0RIUcetEK8LijN1GKsRAzumsQrtOTcnIDWiYICEDGzYAn5qhmJnEME3YCXGCCpGF2gTTWJdroAxs6Z2OJM1lO7WU6NLH6iqrxr2cmM6TnZ1LuptQoCzuFAjMyCkztHiGc10n/UIl14SSU5ISQUYQUNiQYrbLb@PKtb6Sa7xirSnQ1PL8FhgVvXZifiQwII8GDuUzhXaLpAeJPptiMQYALCM0uMfDHACIys2NqFkLMDRwObZpZfuXhX8Qg2OoYJ6u7UJukwth4NiJ2PAwP@rIuBfzlR0dKvadENifp0wqS8unbJPJ6sCNFIwbqchAf7apPMd6m6WCGFAkCutZvCcgnTCNmjVdhoDhc0w@@Aw1xpy2H@gBtrG7sOmtMWHp9spZvpd7xMuoGKaxifiDRiqZ@plhmh6ipF9sr53pHGy/nYKAhcpCISAV6hBYrgD9/8@NJrdz4VBjdn0fj0o2qVlmzQwgMOYjOG6XSXA6u7h1puCZ2TnTYaAvMyDMpgDt2aKnwqli9qKPcZXUQcjNTiVt0GqxWGG/GJLlB0q@nWFnFssrmaa@n/IUiIJFbKwxdNDiHfgxBQ6o3zo2zVbQg3xCgbzcsjF14ZTOrBiB7Y9OYiAsp7ax8VUwwaNCZkSngJ4VbUOqV15trXgDFpgEvlkGnwvC2RESggGS9JIvA9iqcujyBHRsv8EeBZGDvBmjRbwsZ2NoEDzhsZwCSFmS0cAMo5mVMU6rknmmN5AkFM84RYY@2/9Tz@eRIZAXUZ/Jjq@xfuM6zzC6oqSS57wMJKpYFAeQccezpDKWGhweMB24ubCmEg236GS6ZxGLkzMuZu8NRPg4tpdmmIKm0@kNskThuGpdBY8nJ8eZVnwafVma3g2FR0G@xuYevojkR4PwCh/OwNF7l1nAleRxfFuagcbiJczDOds1JZtNqCKbQP4cB2mW1tlqLV4urpF8ngVMluWnYwLZBQsWRz3boYwZD99cOgIks@crTBgSqQyR0/N0jweKDBW4L0BS0oYt4YQBhFRABDi28IyWN8cvSGR3a7Gp5D9y7T6ECnjDgr1iHi6XSfJqNuwsWGZ7Sj6zol9JLGwIdEklIZbYwEXiTXuWFIKhrQrh980qYlfidu4mZfThySleRNKVpUpmdvGmG@/m9nwWtxyofH0JJC2d3tjDl/WhO23qeCPkurqWchWTb6ZCq@uVqeWOAW6upgwml@LsggNbf2Y14UxNq5J6PKacccXkqaG46QiVCslEYGlYh5NOFVQWfW8qLaXCPk@TpZYQJAm6N3irELHAqBJmZpBR0dNinKBRN@pT34DJiwkeTm/2hwyW1GS8B1Ff2APFN9wuVXDkijBwq3BegySpkbWQoBM9j2uiR0mVadxk4U3WSRsio2FKshtj/D6ckkFiusPSOTajGXzWghT6ZyikZ7iWwzLjMXGsAhEhvl0Es@gv6NkuTrTMjJMj98TFR5gZugqfblBPYj/BX8Fbr/u@3bVdwyHJVDWYDdtnZCO96wphonjBCPXFN69LEAOaJ6BKD63M/ghg6OXVmzev39Cvr5XX18R@0bFPW@zes4KUkHmwNw2LxHFruM6DUSWCt1QdNw1q8akZ1GEV0/U8GFjBO5CckG1Z6mKe5JEOWTY0tmkAPiy7kH9GfX4TlrKbs1hmr1za7NZqQDEuAdeD2AJf5EImyYosy1hlblc0x/1NCOeqBTX@bpm2sszqSOEgPgqqiFcHsEugtaNCiGRXAo3ROA27mZClazIu7MEH6zcKK8sqqiD2NPGHjqm7uvENXd7/zO3cUjBwYNfKH7l5Zn0nNdCkbdiQZC3D/jqUmkXiPUarbAZ2Za1QqSwXKtdvLmr94i1ZityRwRZ1gC@VDZPax94gUNTzi0YT39oHccAQZgf@RSLgS3@H@pSMdOIBxOeilfjtxyLZFG9jXiPsjXNtzzFOoBNMpdoVXgTwAEYzdZS8eCbSNwaKWF7MCpFJSW6wAY3VbhZZX1W1sVxpvl0GhGOupYq3GRX@xxQ@0DJkvkjaqCxjLAJoyI3hiyYGhTZVfbO6Uly9aa6uSNXkuTB4CGX/7onHG9a/IUQ3MDiYTkEupxL2OqPlZajwMElVI73bNMR/ppDeJBRXJZN4nYl2PPLzeaLVZwnsqTPQW4jcHRDFrASqpGkavkP0fdVPFSX1eg3ZlYiC/P4P)

Next answer must not exceed 4446 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 70e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  /op.............
00000060: a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1  ................
00000070: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 865c 0a20  .............\. 
00000080: 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e 616d 6520  /+ #\. basename 
00000090: 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20 2f70 726f  "$(readlink /pro
000000a0: 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72 6576 3b3a  c/$$/exe)"|rev;:
000000b0: 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c 0a31 2b2f  <<'EOF' #>>\.1+/
000000c0: 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  //              
000000d0: 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67 6763 476d      O\./* .ggcGm
000000e0: 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f  iV.ZZ;ooo"loG";?
000000f0: 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22  =0%S!11ooo<"><>"
00000100: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 2220 2020  .#define S"C"   
00000110: 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664 6566 205f      //A.#ifdef _
00000120: 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f 6c0a 2066  _cplusplus//l. f
00000130: 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 202f  ();            /
00000140: 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c 6373 7464  /i.#include<cstd
00000150: 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  io>//c.#define S
00000160: 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069 6e74 2f2f  "++C" //e. int//
00000170: 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a 2365 6e64  /         ".#end
00000180: 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c 2e0a 2369  if//       \..#i
00000190: 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364  fdef __OBJC__.#d
000001a0: 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576 6974 6365  efine S"C-evitce
000001b0: 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a 206d 6169  JbO".#endif. mai
000001c0: 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853 292f 2a2f  n(){printf(S)/*/
000001d0: 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374  main(){import st
000001e0: 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974  d.stdio;"D".writ
000001f0: 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a 3e20 2076  e/**/;}/*}<.>  v
00000200: 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5777 7677 5757  wWWWWwWWWWWwvwWW
00000210: 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757 5777 7677  wWWWwvwWWwWWWwvw
00000220: 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757 5777  WWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw
00000230: 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757  vwWWwWWWwvwWWwWW
00000240: 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7757  WwvWwwwwwwwwwwwW
00000250: 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWwWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWwWWWWWWW
00000280: 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWwWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002c0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWw
000002d0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwwwwwWWWWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000300: 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wwwwwWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
00000320: 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039  wwwwww.999 999 9
00000330: 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976  9.999 999 9.999v
00000340: 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031 3130 0a76 2020  <>0000110110.v  
00000350: 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938 222c 2c2c  <>"efunge-98",,,
00000360: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c 2040 0a3e  ,,,,,,7y3-v< @.>
00000370: 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020    #^Gv          
00000380: 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22 5472         @,"B"_"Tr
00000390: 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d 4265  ",,@.   v<[_"]Be
000003a0: 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-93">,,,,,,
000003b0: 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,0|@<.   >#<"
000003c0: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
000003d0: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
000003e0: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
000003f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
00000400: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
00000410: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
00000420: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
00000430: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000440: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
00000450: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000460: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000470: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030  gnuferdauQ"_1000
00000480: 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  00G$v.          
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004a0: 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665      ,,"79-egnufe
000004b0: 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030 3030 3030 4724  tniuQ"_1000000G$
000004c0: 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a  !v@,,,,,,,,,,,,.
000004d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2237 392d              "79-
00000500: 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553 225f 2253 6578  egnufetpeS"_"Sex
00000510: 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c  efunge-97"#@,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c0a 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,,@#,.    
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e22 7622             <>"v"
00000550: 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22 7522 2c22 6e22  @. @,"F","u","n"
00000560: 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22 6f22 2c22 6922  ,"c","t","o","i"
00000570: 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  ,"d"<> red down 
00000580: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
00000590: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e   yellow up green
000005a0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020   down yellow up 
000005b0: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075  green down red u
000005c0: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
000005d0: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
000005e0: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
000005f0: 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f  ue left green do
00000600: 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 6f6e 6520  wn red down one 
00000610: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565  yellow down blue
00000620: 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e   left green down
00000630: 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265   red down two re
00000640: 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f  d left one yello
00000650: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
00000660: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e   blue left green
00000670: 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f   down red left o
00000680: 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7468 7265  ne red down thre
00000690: 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965  e yellow down ye
000006a0: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c  llow down blue l
000006b0: 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072  eft green down r
000006c0: 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20 6772 6565 6e20  ed up two green 
000006d0: 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079  down yellow up y
000006e0: 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520  ellow down blue 
000006f0: 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265  left red up thre
00000700: 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20  e red right two 
00000710: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c  yellow down yell
00000720: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
00000730: 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030  t 00011100001000
00000740: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000750: 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030  0010100000100000
00000760: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000770: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000780: 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030  0010100000100000
00000790: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000100000100010
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010000000001000
000007b0: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3131  1000001000100011
000007c0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001100001000
000007e0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  1000001000001000
00000800: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000810: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
00000820: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130  0000100010000010
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3131  0010001000000011
00000840: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3031 3130 3030  0000110000011000
00000850: 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010011000001000
00000860: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  1000100010001000
00000870: 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030  0001001101110000
00000880: 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3031 3130  0011001111000110
00000890: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3031 3131  0110000000100111
000008a0: 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030 3131 3031 3131  0011110000110111
000008b0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008c0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008d0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008e0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008f0: 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031 3131 3130 3030  0110001101111000
00000900: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130  1000100010000010
00000910: 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030  0010100001000000
00000920: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0100010000000100
00000930: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
00000940: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
00000950: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000010000000010
00000960: 3031 3130 0a2e 4c20 2020 202e 202e 2020  0110..L    . .  
00000970: 2020 2020 2020 202a 2f2f 2f7b 7d5d e28e         *///{}]..
00000980: 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63 7261 6843 c2ab  ......laocrahC..
00000990: e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82  ................
000009a0: e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f e286 a8c2 b2c2  ................
000009b0: b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690 c39f e289 a4e2  ................
000009c0: 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286 90e2 89a5 e286  ................
000009d0: 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
000009e0: 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
000009f0: e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a00: 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692  ................
00000a10: e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000a20: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a30: b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf  ................
00000a40: 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c 82e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
00000a50: c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000a60: c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a70: a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1ce  ................
00000a80: b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80c2 a1e2  ................
00000a90: 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000aa0: e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb4 c2a1  ................
00000ab0: cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1  ................
00000ac0: ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1 c2bb 2b5b 2d2b  ............+[-+
00000ad0: 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d  +++[-<+++++>]<[-
00000ae0: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  <++++++<+++++<++
00000af0: 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  +++>>>]<<<++++++
00000b00: 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d  +.>-.>---.<<----
00000b10: 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d  -.++++++++.-----
00000b20: 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e  .>--.>---.<+.>>>
00000b30: 5d28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928  ]((((((((((()()(
00000b40: 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929  )){}){}){}){}())
00000b50: 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d  {})((()()()()){}
00000b60: 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b  ){})[(([][]){}){
00000b70: 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d  }()])([]()){})[]
00000b80: 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d  ())(([[][]()]([]
00000b90: 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b  ()((((([][][])){
00000ba0: 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829  }{})[]){})))[]()
00000bb0: 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 2821 293d  )({ -}_=")";(!)=
00000bc0: 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574 2062 215f  seq;main|let b!_
00000bd0: 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222 2122  =""=putStr$(""!"
00000be0: 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22 292b  snrettaPgnaB+")+
00000bf0: 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b 7361 4828 227b  +init"lleksaH("{
00000c00: 2d0a 2f2f 4848 542d 224e 5562 3460 424a  -.//HHT-"NUb4`BJ
00000c10: 4a6e 644f 2d7d 2d2d 295b 2d5d 3c3e 5c5b  JndO-}--)[-]<>\[
00000c20: 5c3c 3e5c 5c2f 3c3e 5c2f 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c  \<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\
00000c30: 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 2f3c 3e5c  <><><>\[/\/\/<>\
00000c40: 2f2f 5c2f 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5c  //\/<><><><><>\\
00000c50: 5d2f 5c2f 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f 5c5d 2f5c 2f5c  ]/\//\//\/\]/\/\
00000c60: 5c2e 2f5d 732a 2f2f e288 9953 4156 4e41  \./]s*//...SAVNA
00000c70: 43ef bd90 f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92  C.......ijome...
00000c80: ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d  ........Emotinom
00000c90: 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac e28f  icon............
00000ca0: a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e  .@,ka"89-egnufen
00000cb0: 5573 7373 7373 6161 6161 6165 6565 6565  Usssssaaaaaeeeee
00000cc0: 6565 6565 6570 6165 6565 6565 6565 6565  eeeeepaeeeeeeeee
00000cd0: 6563 6973 6165 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969  ecisaeeeeeeejiii
00000ce0: 6969 6969 696a 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  iiiiijeeeeeeeeee
00000cf0: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 6969 6969  eeeeeeeejiiiiiii
00000d00: 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6565 6565 656a  iiiiiijeeeeeeeej
00000d10: 6969 6969 6a69 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969  iiiijiiiiiiiiiii
00000d20: 6a7a 6165 6565 6165 6561 6577 7575 7577  jzaeeeaeeaewuuuw
00000d30: 6565 6565 6561 6161 616b 6565 6161 6161  eeeeeaaaakeeaaaa
00000d40: 7776 77e2 a080 e2a0 96e2 a097 e2a0 8ee2  wvw.............
00000d50: a28e e2a2 a6e2 a2a6 e2a0 ae22            ..........."
```

Thank to @Potato44 for the tip about "sandwiching" the emojis (and symbolic brainfuck) between the code and the data section of the braille code.

Answer (score 4):

## 44. BrainFlaX86, 3662 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
.L    . .         *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>](()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-"NUb4`BJJndO-}--)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijzaeeeaeeaewuuuweeeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbchvHlc@cX8hLc0ALMwQGQ5ASRUIAwrskryQyoixpDUDwYKYBDDmYgecCkqKZcm2qVJuqrTiVB@/lYS1v7ab2kmxVXPHD1npflHf7H/gDyR9oz@nuueBCSXYyJGa6z71Pn76cxqBjBP3Xr3Nk07KIQWjPiHqucY@EHtSGnnPWc7yQhDQISd/wXRoEpHNGHth05zk9OvY6Uo5se45jDANK5G3PojIxXIvIm34vGlA3DGQSUDO0PTcgXc8nHRqG1Cf0dEh9m7omlSTTCEmdmMArOS7RAlZkt1KnS3Jki3Yjt0e19RUp9CKzT4a@DYIlUG13yZkXEQNtjxUWycA4piSIfIqtGHiW3T0jYEFpeEYCj4R90Bf26RmwUGK7phNZ1IICAolju8cSNfse0VwiL5RlMI3zZqDLCLW8YBy6gtDAGwyo1rVPx3HXEfe4NDRCsy9Jw7Ow77krs4lv@0YQVKTQJ5ppkZMnI1JlvkE8ttn0BkPbodA9rGk22D6ifgAeJl6XbPmG7d4xzGOisOKeYzxdWyX048geGQ74R5U6HUR0HQNoVHIuETI4tmzomhisdbzIBZ8AxhwS3RuGOsP1Qay@WOoHs0mtmeAA7NNskg/0ptJ4ZmjPN7UPW031rhvSHvX1ZhlKK8t6L08Wx6hDLybp@t6AlX3DmaZLsG@hXLbtwdDzQ7JjhEYJqDi61zdTn0HTeENKJeki66e6btGR7kaOQ5br18qSJN3bfHD7g83bu@27D3Z2n9bK0tZfP9o9rMkLyokJHce6TJUliFwW/MQx3F5k9KiinktzrKvlHFkYl1IiC@UiWWCSYJTBoJNj2oeR69puj7CAvLYszXVg2IIeFox1LwqHUSjNQcyAdwk4mVQJB0LY8YLmmEIYC8jzcrF4IX/i01Edx6IZQmcJXbNwmutIczDa5ok5GKYSSYwn165diQPeWzi2XGmOa3jie9AUTlgid@ipFQ2GFcCenlokbkvXluYmnAzOVSZcViirauIkjTQ/WlBwOuFC1OZHOKyZz@rxrHGBY6gfhsOgous9O@xHnRIMKf2Rf3Y33Hdh/FM99M/s0IvLlOoDI4BZSz/xjSHMW4EU9yaRd2QiWwMIMT9y2ZwlZ5CHOL6BwI9gzmTjiI14fi/5nSmGerUO5PH0wDi6dtBnN5y@Jum3gZpRmVpomnrHdnV4zjZmG@Zv0zOchEXUk8IsBY/tAdCP7EEyL0O5FEI/TwwJDAD0vEBnZex33scVYEQ1NLeH9p0Sr3MkgCaXq3lZGFMBIkv6BDArOFkY1uI2dRII80W307GnmpQuJxNcjAXK3J5PSGjYDg6xwsp6ln8PAmJn/5Bs798nXZiIMx3Gl4Qs8W3PmdGnPc9h3Rr4Zlye5fwP3GwDh2esQjQtCK3a@hoUIkFwdRtvTnnmpjYIu7aON5AQA6@WsPoWCQl4dUoGnz8j8zgREQPS0hTTI/8tjQ79KxrNZGo4X4/pY6tWuizyYNscY4S5VOaPKaF3jOCYOg4bxCCKVaaInjP@5zPY6cA7sie7nwH5fVa3C5WFLYAcGLhdcoNx/drTLG56pBcKONAKBRxoJjziAWYOh@nAEpUs4@7AC23XG9im54IEmMBxwXywv7PbPth8dKfWlPUo8HXH7uguiGzDBiRyaNCUUSJCkvYlYsYqpaNpY4@Z745n@M7i3WLN6pY0St45wt8QOZuObY7P0wZCdFgwqD/0KdxnzdY/iQzrh9jxcco3JXN9PZazvq7Dkk/DM7zP0I3G/RDdCd@UzOBs0PGg4SQ7cAee64m1q9PFT4mectZZSwCjZlt3oBpbCqH@/a0NYq5pW2F9pkEsidf0EJIAGuo@dagRUAGdXpXpMPxBtgyvctwe7vI824qFdUU9KUxxsE3@WMT1EMLvs2LNcIb9mTOpQJCS7eJ2CjabY1PB5oPHm4fAlY5O03BHRsAG8Kzx6BoDcB@keTEoVhkjdMsOwIDIdqwUlnBNTYAjGyfPI2NkwFrqQOsgB@qLeQJwhN2mth3AgrsJkTHBYsyfjG2kdWFOMfTHmInArMaeM2IxM2EyklnrhePQrEuhGj@nV8Q0nZLjtS2T6mSWGG1TMEtsz9kl@aZbhWmkzrKCej7J/3D/jkmxidtUb0hdJY8UebXkU8NS1ArjV0zMcz3fUky1XltZxvya16rl5ZtYM2HyDUFGvlq/tpCnDuTi3fy13DmnuriVL1LXquXzsFWOLarqzJaqjnY13aZ7wLbHFSzmWUou9suCQW66DdgiExs212xjPN9qPLq730L6B/Q0hKw/OIHEfhAFIbOGnpoU8gLcsrOEpl5eWfkxLy6WV/TyUoVXCteXVJVnOyUUlsvFGQHWZAlzAjT1E0zkIN97phO49HzGt8yQSrKpx3Qd@l7P5VJP8xT@9esRDkZ9UTvXNJLrP5x/qm2Qg2f9n/706cbG0g5Z2pH7Iw78sE8KT28Q@f78fUId6ID7@9vkcH@HUn9v4aIAV2NR1yFyLl@@uPzyxbvcmxLRCyQHD9hqUBwykGwp2NV46kCgKzxTX1jQYdJTWfp1q1Kt5nf39/IkV683pXIBFJKpa78p6YvkR72eeXtgP/7Rhx/e8jxPdrzb8q0f15beO5wvlwFQZcmFlLNoF9eTQ8wd@KXrm1LO7gKCtNvm0IkC/Oi6I5Guot7KqtJ1G0j5kUnVhC2Z7dV13cxILRRArq5TCcIxzJoLqiEI7W4CapZSrftb72@321njNJgXQpO@39mPGSUygAEG@TPveOVQ1Rd1ARKpPRhUYkbdgrysdOLbIdUXF/VbF/riRVWqEzI6eQIXuz05wcrJ9y88OUmvRFj8SJ7Z0nhlDH4F5B1BT05mAZ8ktl2BenI1il/S@vo64Z@0iKVRtb4EV7mM/9KIEAipdLtejK@bZyvaqEo20OW5Z7dHUyG7UZS35Dbs4oBnQwLAqNpoy61MalZPhBWXPtmoIk09V82mJXXybLRwG4xBOxihfHNdoz036tItmbSnB8qIxQAj3chxUIbHfyS3RzmCIpfK1bpE3nhV62X0xO2FESfMbRTHro1cRrJlRD@R24wh5bjyyjYkdO2UFXjnR2N63iJp/MpIHdJDcP/Ynmy8ARu5t8qGrh/J0HnQl3tyUY7g48LHhE8IHw8@NnwsuVonPszdlnfikvDEYxWHdnEhoeQMlmfvhERD0oO82uVUM4HIBpCwDyBW8e1eP2QSBX2Wl5U7TkS5qgk5rJBR/w7Ub7D8nYQkfKlE1pLvbTv6AGyZ6a7ZAv4sz7HhzuKPB2F5rIT3bC1L8S7003TTcjK48hXyy2@SuPQWje@gN8aU03vyyJamPgmB8CEnLvNaOeUVZCkuy5Mh@d7PWFGsckb7ylM8P1CfaKpUuofzQwn@4gt3SucXrctf/NMfv/n1q/9xDM/0jf72q/@6/PyrV8nf5d/9zeWLf//2d3D7wxdwS2GXL34JkJ//6@Xn31y@@BW7//Ly5/@GZYb/7mdYFP@MOa1992mmJmCvvvzDF6@@TKrf/n4GI6P7epzruxdI/TWIZGrHxQiST8GYz7@KCb772auvBQnUvv1dWv7uUygDIfsfKzIBQPx7pjCGc9jX2PjPv3n15av/LTQ0tg3Vqvgo1FvVuFioZu71OmCqAlEo1TX417RStarhVSrECF6tazEeSIFTUdT4T63WFfE8V84vGoraQhCW1bh@AeVq/YJRniNEqZ5fKOnFBQFR/M9rSqJGIBqK0mg1WjFNS4UqR7InYBGN8vHORCMAOICGUSGtyqnrzKxzEFRVxq@/kDkNZoSKCCBKarzO/hjPuM6s4gYnZoYq50S7aNdkVb6lzKu1gH58C3e5nzg0JJ15QMg1SPQPQ39BkeV5OXB9GobGQc81tgqyWijYrh3KkMAeB8YdRT7XJF2/c@eRJj/4oHP9o63333etfe1C09SG1qrWm40m3Jo63PRmQ4dbtY5/vMzA7BH/NZstnYEQjcVms6S3Ahjfl3/7j4ebjx9sbv/x/375py9@9Rv7yBtQLFz@85d/@uIffps9W4T6V5ef/eflZ7@5/Ow/NorHhrwWb03cDwK8DLxocg0zZdMO4tqRLa4jOnUluHECBs7ijp6jNAP/T6IoOmFUqP2YP2Dnf/ny08uXn1@@/PvLl7@4/Bf4/zX@v/xv@TV@4UieO3aH8AxkURKZCCZ4q9elbs0xBh3LIG6FpfduMe93kvResmqdPJ46N0@7XfzkC10lX2LHZ5Cw5tVCJ5@ieDlfOvIg5ekqeyqeHOxBmtXghwbFPE9yocC/h4BC9gtmqIrjlHxLlcwafo/s0yDwOkfKenFnd@/e5qPdnaJ2f/Np@8nW3UeHCGvf373fvrf7ePdecUnlKbfC21bqrF6nLmpWzFIsS7HUglnqQvrYV9RiJ7@hQ2Mtyqig1UHo20MlX8ur6usc2dk/1Bz7mJLTtVUygLAdGA6hg8gxQnxRYOItA8jA8fv55JWEE88/Dkif@rSIhxIntuMwGB6lgHsdFF@EfvB9/N60E/UCLgRoLY8Gbp6LEBLwLQJIvztGxzkjLh5chB6hpyFknsCRvmnAUH3qDEFh2BcUqCDs2wExOtBCg33hWyRGcEwGNH6vwMSecMMAv6PHXSA8Bmfi0ASALhdg9g0YubAjl@JACs4CiUUZP0r0nECEGhkafmgbjiQxSzKnRzzGQD/pVqQ5aFXPNwakRrpx2A3owPPPANJ4AKa0Fldv3FhZFdDG8o3VCnwKYIYieNUW0IqyZFEnKUs@7dn4zWgABOf5uwf5Clk6hV1AkeQP72Yq209ZZWlpb68ozeV3sIq6ke4gLe/cjctAtBnzMAlbGZatmOVC6jpGjyvf3gPgnuEESLGfrXyYrRxmKwdJ5UKS8CSC@r7nK4OgpzLPYbR35d2HD/cfVsg5gC/gkbR53r@QVWkOeqhET@1QKatcSI@GbeyINh5qKSgJC2Ck8HAioIEea7XYF@uMBCIAm1URduQhPzOjEMMLjxjxaMQSQvKgeEIOKdRIGaFh5LtM3oQ5J3gciOY4HhgzYaU017dnQYU4BbDVKllTSYE4niQ93L19iAGEvcT7F7uP3bfYHbqV9xQPBd65LeS7s3lvD3nP4z5WuBDWD2qR5MjmPUBtc9T2OGr7Xhw@CleXonYQtcVRW@OoLUSxQBO6HvmRUHUHmQ5SVQlmGzEsiIWmBLODmJ27qaIEs3VHEoEEk6HnjNg3ZP5gjXndHxQB3IOWjyHLq@hmnJgC2w1CwzWpgqQwkyAXsAFH7LaGP2ixjh@D0V4r6SihZYYVqAgEsvKsnt7aPNzFLm3EPQj9VSRxbSeuHYzhDrK4GJqhjSVglMM02I5jltt/2ODW6DpZI@@RtRYzjw2VGA6LKHcBhwARcxYnq5EV5iLedCYQHFQkWU3SHJ6HIxmuWyBoCYq4dKIXYXLGZiMXUqDkdFShX6eGZOQGNEyIUIANC4BPzVCMTGKYJqyEOECFykJtQmhsyzUwBpb0bleS5rKNWkpsGWB1lVXjVk4M58nGziXNTThQFw8KRGb0lBlZPMK5rZNxoZJrwsgpTYkiIwgoLEix2OU3SeVWXyk1nrHWFAC1Pb8NTsWonRgfCQ7Yo6FD@UihvSLp270@G2IxBSAsIzR4xMMYAIzK3Y2kWQ8wMgg5tmhl25fFvxejY6wQns7tQm@LK2HoOIhY97A46sq4FvOZHQMqjp0QxJ@nQipLy6dskcnawJ0UjDupyFB/tqs8x3qTp4IYUSQKa1m8JiCfcI2adV2GgdFzSt75jDSmnPYf2AG@sXuw6K0xZenyykW@U3jE06joprGB@IN6Khn6mW6a7qKkXWytnRkcbL2dwoCHysIgYBXmEJiugPwvF0aTy7kIqDG/vktEJYvULLdmOhAE8x4c98skOh1d3DtT@MzonBkw0JYZGOZTwPZt0VIRVLF40ca4Suqg5Ga3kgK0WqxW@C/GZOWBkW8W2J0l8kqhaeynMgWhEBE7a4wcrHgLfcyBHeq3j0yzHfQhn1AgL7dsTF04pzNrj8DWRydxEJZT39j45pyQUSEzdqdAnlVtQ6pXXm2veEO2MQl8swwxF4Szd0iIBkzSSj4NIFTl2OUJ7Nh6gy0KIgdlM0GL@FjO7qFB8UTEcg5gZUlGAzOMVlbHOK9K5pndwJJwfMg5MvzZ9p96Pt8ZAnsR7Zls@BprN87zjKInSip5xsvAoopJcQgZdzxKKmOpweEBs4G7C2sq0XCJToZ7lrA4OeJi8d5QbB/H1tKMULB0Or1BkagcZ62r8PHg5DTThk@TL0vTq6GIKMjX2NjD97b8aBheEcMZPEbvMttwJXkcX5ZmkLH9EubhXOyaks0mVJFNoHxOgzxL62y2Fu9i10g@zzZMluWnfQLZBdssnvTxtX4UxrdvLj0BIrPvK0wZMqmMkPPzdI9vFBkpSF@ApKQDS8IxQwitQAh4hPCMloPjV0Kyq7VYVPIfuPYAtgp4YMF@GREul0nyJjusLFhma0o@M6NfySx8CHxJJWGWWMdF4gciLCkER1sVws/NKmJV4n7uJWWM4ckhXkTWlaVKZnRx0I23S3s2S1oOTL6@BJqWTm/s4W9MoDkd6ngnKHV1LZUqBt9Mg1bXK1PTHUPcXE0FTE7F2QkHlv7MbMKFmlYljXhMOeOKyVNDcegIlQrJ7MDSbR0OOlVwWfSdubSUC9s8zZZ6QrAk5N7wjUrEBKNKmJlBRkVPi3GCRt1oQH0DBi8meDi82e@IWFKTiR4kfW4PFd9we1TBnitCx63CfQ2SpEbWQ4JPtDyuiRYlVWZxi21vskHaEBkNM5IdjPFzOCVDxGyHqXNsRDP8rAkp9M9QSd9wLYdlxmPqWAV2hPg@FYyiv6JnuzjQMiNOjtxjF7@0zfBV@HCDerL3E/IVPHrd9@2e7RoOSYaqwXzYOSMb6akrbBPFK1VoL76oXoI9oHkMpvTRy@x3E4ZeXr158/oN/fpaeX1NrBdd@7TNzp4V5ITMg72YWSSOW8N5HpwqETxSddx0U4vfE0IdZjFdz4ODFTyB5IxsyVIX8ySPfCiyobFFA@hh2oX8MxrwQ1jKDmexzN5QtdnRakBxXwKhB3sLfHUNhSQzsixjlYVd0RyPN6GcmxbU@Nt02soyqyOHg/SoqCJelsAmgdWOClskuxJojMdp2K2ELZ2TcWIP3lu/UVhZVtEEsaaJ379MnerGB7q8/Znj3FIwdGDVyjfdPPO@kzpo0jesS7KeYb94S90i8RajVzYDu7JWqFSWC5XrNxe1QfGWLEXuicEmdcAvlQ2T2kfeMFDU84tGC3/kAOpAIIwO/EVJwKf@LvUpOdGJBxifq1bil0WLZFO8vHqN/wZL23OMY2gEM6l2RRQBPoDeTAMlL74TGRhDRUwvZoXIpCQ3WIfGZreKrK2q2liutN6sA7ZjrqWK9zcV/jse3tEyZL7I2qgs414EyFAaoxcghgWYqr5eXSmu3jRXV6Rq8k04RAhlP4aK@xvmP/z5HnQOplOQy6mEvcBpeRkuvExS1Uj/Ng3xhzykP4nFWckkXncCjld@Pk@0@iyFfXUGeRuJe0OimJVAlTRNw7emvq/5qaGkXq@huBJRUN7/Aw)

Next answer must not exceed 4760 bytes.

### Explanation

[BrainFlaX86](https://github.com/bforte/BrainFlaX86) is a Brain-Flak compiler that uses 32bit integers (*[-2147483648,2147483647]*) while the classic Brain-Flak uses unbounded integers, the code tests the result of `2^32`:

```
push 5
(()()()()())
push 2
<>(()())
do 32 times
<>{({}[()])
    square the value
    <>({({})({}[()])}{})
<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFPb4MgFL/zKV56WKGJktrssjQmW3bYPsAuq12CQitRwQH2sMbP7qjWZrZNBpfH7w@P3yNlNu@6jDmIIdNcIJSmhkm1K1kBmMARAVQFlwYucJDqRnHBPZPVQHXtaM/lLCvoIsztfSm/C1vBIZAwtzTBmy8W/DwHn9uEvCsn9sLQZOmrVUT3c1hM1E6Pkp3RVV8bVt7qLuw/ykjKqtbGwStzLPSqgd7nGbycnv3mw/loQ5AwRO1kUDHl4kBVU5YQxQ9LhFBtpHI7mH2oc1aQwyvsE8zQ1dAuHc5fMJoTtYpS6f5YJ2uGbiZ6dVXX1Y3N4RFhTMZNUI9FaB3j4cw1rCJwshLWg0d8bDeYbAk69bDfDTMCXC7gwMpG9KB3nlRkVLa@9s52Hf8C)

From there it's just a conditional statement which tests for zero.

**Note:** The test harness just compiles a patched version of BrainHack to emulate the behaviour of BrainFlaX86 since TIO doesn't include it.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 70e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  /op.............
00000060: a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1  ................
00000070: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 865c 0a20  .............\. 
00000080: 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e 616d 6520  /+ #\. basename 
00000090: 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20 2f70 726f  "$(readlink /pro
000000a0: 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72 6576 3b3a  c/$$/exe)"|rev;:
000000b0: 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c 0a31 2b2f  <<'EOF' #>>\.1+/
000000c0: 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  //              
000000d0: 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67 6763 476d      O\./* .ggcGm
000000e0: 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f  iV.ZZ;ooo"loG";?
000000f0: 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22  =0%S!11ooo<"><>"
00000100: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 2220 2020  .#define S"C"   
00000110: 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664 6566 205f      //A.#ifdef _
00000120: 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f 6c0a 2066  _cplusplus//l. f
00000130: 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 202f  ();            /
00000140: 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c 6373 7464  /i.#include<cstd
00000150: 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  io>//c.#define S
00000160: 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069 6e74 2f2f  "++C" //e. int//
00000170: 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a 2365 6e64  /         ".#end
00000180: 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c 2e0a 2369  if//       \..#i
00000190: 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364  fdef __OBJC__.#d
000001a0: 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576 6974 6365  efine S"C-evitce
000001b0: 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a 206d 6169  JbO".#endif. mai
000001c0: 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853 292f 2a2f  n(){printf(S)/*/
000001d0: 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374  main(){import st
000001e0: 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974  d.stdio;"D".writ
000001f0: 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a 3e20 2076  e/**/;}/*}<.>  v
00000200: 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5777 7677 5757  wWWWWwWWWWWwvwWW
00000210: 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757 5777 7677  wWWWwvwWWwWWWwvw
00000220: 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757 5777  WWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw
00000230: 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777 5757  vwWWwWWWwvwWWwWW
00000240: 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7757  WwvWwwwwwwwwwwwW
00000250: 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWwWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWwWWWWWWW
00000280: 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWwWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWwWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002c0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWw
000002d0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwwwwwWWWWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000300: 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wwwwwWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
00000320: 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039  wwwwww.999 999 9
00000330: 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976  9.999 999 9.999v
00000340: 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031 3130 0a76 2020  <>0000110110.v  
00000350: 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938 222c 2c2c  <>"efunge-98",,,
00000360: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c 2040 0a3e  ,,,,,,7y3-v< @.>
00000370: 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020    #^Gv          
00000380: 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22 5472         @,"B"_"Tr
00000390: 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d 4265  ",,@.   v<[_"]Be
000003a0: 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-93">,,,,,,
000003b0: 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,0|@<.   >#<"
000003c0: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
000003d0: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
000003e0: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
000003f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
00000400: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
00000410: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
00000420: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
00000430: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000440: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
00000450: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000460: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000470: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030  gnuferdauQ"_1000
00000480: 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  00G$v.          
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004a0: 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665      ,,"79-egnufe
000004b0: 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030 3030 3030 4724  tniuQ"_1000000G$
000004c0: 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a  !v@,,,,,,,,,,,,.
000004d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2237 392d              "79-
00000500: 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553 225f 2253 6578  egnufetpeS"_"Sex
00000510: 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c  efunge-97"#@,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c0a 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,,@#,.    
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e22 7622             <>"v"
00000550: 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22 7522 2c22 6e22  @. @,"F","u","n"
00000560: 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22 6f22 2c22 6922  ,"c","t","o","i"
00000570: 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  ,"d"<> red down 
00000580: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
00000590: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e   yellow up green
000005a0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020   down yellow up 
000005b0: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075  green down red u
000005c0: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
000005d0: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
000005e0: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
000005f0: 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f  ue left green do
00000600: 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 6f6e 6520  wn red down one 
00000610: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565  yellow down blue
00000620: 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e   left green down
00000630: 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265   red down two re
00000640: 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f  d left one yello
00000650: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
00000660: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e   blue left green
00000670: 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f   down red left o
00000680: 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7468 7265  ne red down thre
00000690: 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965  e yellow down ye
000006a0: 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c  llow down blue l
000006b0: 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072  eft green down r
000006c0: 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20 6772 6565 6e20  ed up two green 
000006d0: 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079  down yellow up y
000006e0: 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520  ellow down blue 
000006f0: 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265  left red up thre
00000700: 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20  e red right two 
00000710: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c  yellow down yell
00000720: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
00000730: 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030  t 00011100001000
00000740: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000750: 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030  0010100000100000
00000760: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000770: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000780: 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030  0010100000100000
00000790: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000100000100010
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010000000001000
000007b0: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3131  1000001000100011
000007c0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001100001000
000007e0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  1000001000001000
00000800: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000810: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
00000820: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130  0000100010000010
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3131  0010001000000011
00000840: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3031 3130 3030  0000110000011000
00000850: 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010011000001000
00000860: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  1000100010001000
00000870: 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030  0001001101110000
00000880: 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3031 3130  0011001111000110
00000890: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3031 3131  0110000000100111
000008a0: 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030 3131 3031 3131  0011110000110111
000008b0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008c0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008d0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008e0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
000008f0: 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031 3131 3130 3030  0110001101111000
00000900: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130  1000100010000010
00000910: 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030  0010100001000000
00000920: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0100010000000100
00000930: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
00000940: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030  0000010000000100
00000950: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130  0000010000000010
00000960: 3031 3130 0a2e 4c20 2020 202e 202e 2020  0110..L    . .  
00000970: 2020 2020 2020 202a 2f2f 2f7b 7d5d e28e         *///{}]..
00000980: 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63 7261 6843 c2ab  ......laocrahC..
00000990: e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82  ................
000009a0: e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f e286 a8c2 b2c2  ................
000009b0: b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690 c39f e289 a4e2  ................
000009c0: 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286 90e2 89a5 e286  ................
000009d0: 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
000009e0: 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
000009f0: e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a00: 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692  ................
00000a10: e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000a20: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a30: b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf  ................
00000a40: 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c 82e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
00000a50: c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000a60: c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a70: a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1ce  ................
00000a80: b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80c2 a1e2  ................
00000a90: 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000aa0: e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb4 c2a1  ................
00000ab0: cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1  ................
00000ac0: ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1 c2bb 2b5b 2d2b  ............+[-+
00000ad0: 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d  +++[-<+++++>]<[-
00000ae0: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  <++++++<+++++<++
00000af0: 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  +++>>>]<<<++++++
00000b00: 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d  +.>-.>---.<<----
00000b10: 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d  -.++++++++.-----
00000b20: 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e  .>--.>---.<+.>>>
00000b30: 5d28 2829 2829 2829 2829 2829 293c 3e28  ](()()()()())<>(
00000b40: 2829 2829 293c 3e7b 287b 7d5b 2829 5d29  ()())<>{({}[()])
00000b50: 3c3e 287b 287b 7d29 287b 7d5b 2829 5d29  <>({({})({}[()])
00000b60: 7d7b 7d29 3c3e 7d3c 3e28 2829 7b5b 2829  }{})<>}<>((){[()
00000b70: 5d28 3c7b 7d28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  ](<{}(((((((((((
00000b80: 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b  )()()){}){}){}){
00000b90: 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928  }()){})((()()()(
00000ba0: 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29  )){}){})[(([][])
00000bb0: 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b  {}){}()])([]()){
00000bc0: 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829  })[]())(([[][]()
00000bd0: 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b  ]([]()((((([][][
00000be0: 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929  ])){}{})[]){})))
00000bf0: 5b5d 2829 293e 297d 7b7d 297b 7b7d 283c  []())>)}{}){{}(<
00000c00: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829  ((((((((((((((()
00000c10: 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  ()()){}){}){}){}
00000c20: 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829  ()){})((()()()()
00000c30: 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b  ){}){})[(([][]){
00000c40: 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d  }){}()])([]()){}
00000c50: 295b 5d28 2929 5b5b 5d28 2928 2928 295d  )[]())[[]()()()]
00000c60: 295b 5d29 5b5b 5d28 2928 2928 2928 295d  )[])[[]()()()()]
00000c70: 295b 5d5b 5d5b 5d5b 2829 5d29 2828 2828  )[][][][()])((((
00000c80: 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d  ((()()()){}()){}
00000c90: 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2829 2829 5d29 3e29  ){}){})[()()])>)
00000ca0: 7d7b 7d28 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 2821  }{}({ -}_=")";(!
00000cb0: 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574 2062  )=seq;main|let b
00000cc0: 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222  !_=""=putStr$(""
00000cd0: 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22  !"snrettaPgnaB+"
00000ce0: 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b 7361 4828  )++init"lleksaH(
00000cf0: 227b 2d0a 2f2f 4848 542d 224e 5562 3460  "{-.//HHT-"NUb4`
00000d00: 424a 4a6e 644f 2d7d 2d2d 295b 2d5d 3c3e  BJJndO-}--)[-]<>
00000d10: 5c5b 5c3c 3e5c 5c2f 3c3e 5c2f 5c5b 2f5c  \[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\
00000d20: 2f5c 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 2f3c  /\<><><>\[/\/\/<
00000d30: 3e5c 2f2f 5c2f 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e  >\//\/<><><><><>
00000d40: 5c5c 5d2f 5c2f 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f 5c5d 2f5c  \\]/\//\//\/\]/\
00000d50: 2f5c 5c2e 2f5d 732a 2f2f e288 9953 4156  /\\./]s*//...SAV
00000d60: 4e41 43ef bd90 f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0  NAC.......ijome.
00000d70: 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e  ..........Emotin
00000d80: 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac  omicon..........
00000d90: e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  ...@,ka"89-egnuf
00000da0: 656e 5573 7373 7373 6161 6161 6165 6565  enUsssssaaaaaeee
00000db0: 6565 6565 6565 6570 6165 6565 6565 6565  eeeeeeepaeeeeeee
00000dc0: 6565 6563 6973 6165 6565 6565 6565 6a69  eeecisaeeeeeeeji
00000dd0: 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565 6565 6565 6565  iiiiiiijeeeeeeee
00000de0: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6a69 6969 6969  eeeeeeeeeejiiiii
00000df0: 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6565 6565  iiiiiiiijeeeeeee
00000e00: 656a 6969 6969 6a69 6969 6969 6969 6969  ejiiiijiiiiiiiii
00000e10: 6969 6a7a 6165 6565 6165 6561 6577 7575  iijzaeeeaeeaewuu
00000e20: 7577 6565 6565 6561 6161 616b 6565 6161  uweeeeeaaaakeeaa
00000e30: 6161 7776 77e2 a080 e2a0 96e2 a097 e2a0  aawvw...........
00000e40: 8ee2 a28e e2a2 a6e2 a2a6 e2a0 ae22       ............."
```

Answer (score 4):

## 47. Minkolang, 3820 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M eliF MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///opfzzfzzfzzfzzzfzzfzfzfffzffzzzzzffzfzzzffzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzfffzzfzfzzzfzffff⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 & I8 H I  d      $$$
a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP<
>"gnalokniM"OOOOOOOOO.
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
01 & && &&&     & {}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>](()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")";x--?y
 =y;y="yrruC";(!)=seq;main=let b!_=""in putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++y--?"lleksaH"
--N'Zi(Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*///∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejzaciiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaceeacewuuuweejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `eliF MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86
- `NOOPS` in Spoon
- `yrruC` in Curry
- `gnalokniM` in Minkolang

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbchvHlc@cX8hLa0gTMwQGQ5ASRYIAwrskryQyoixpBUDIYKYBDDEXZC4AIZou16bKtanail158F4e1vbWbmovyVbFFT9sbfZFeY//gT@Q/IH2nO654UJJdjIkZrrPvU@fvpzGoK35vdevF8muYRCN0K4Wdh3tPglcqA1ca9y13IAE1A9IT/Mc6vukPSYPTXrwkp713bawSPZdy9IGPiXivmtQkWiOQcRdrxva1Al8kfhUD0zX8UnH9UibBgH1CD0fUM@kjk4FQdcCUiM68AqWQxSfFdmt2O6QRbJHO6HTpcrW@gze7ltA8MB0@q6lOV0hcEO9RwaeCYoFMM3skLEbEg3bFhtUILbWp8QPPYqttF3D7IwJWFgcjInvkqAH9gQ9OgYWSkxHt0KDGlBAILFAl0D1nksUh4hLJRFM57wZ6BpCDdefhK4j1Hdtmyod83wSdxNxT4oDLdB7gjAYBz3XWZ9PfMfTfL8sBB5RdIOMng5JhfkO8dhm3bUHpkWh@1jTTLB9SD0feoC4HbLnaaZzV9P7RGLFI0t7trlB6E9Cc6hZ4B9ZaLcR0bE0oJHJhUCI3TdM6LoYrLTd0AGfAEYfENUdBCrD9UCsulLs@fNJjblgH@xTTJLz1YZUf6EpL3eV582GfM8JaJd6aqMEpfU1tZsjKxPUgRuTdDzXZmVPs2bpEuxbKNdM0x64XkAOtEArAhVHd3t66jNoGm9IsShcZv1UUw06VJ3QsshabbkkCML93Yd3Pti9c9i69/Dg8Fm1JOz99ePD06q4JI106DjWZbIoQGSzwUEwfEOtSyX5QlhgXS0ukqVJKUWyVCqQJSYJRiEMSjGmfRQ6jul0CQvI5TVhoQ3DGvSwYKy5YTAIA2EBYga8S8DJpEI4EMKOFxRLj4SxgLwoFQqX4oceHdZwrOoBdFakax5OcSxhAUbbDaLbg1QiifFkeflaHPBu49hyhAWu4annQlM4YZHcpedGaA/KgD0/N0jclo4pLEw5GZwrTbksX5LlxEkKafx4ScLphguRGz/GYc18VotnjUscQ70gGPhlVe2aQS9sF2FIqY@98b3g2IHxT9XAG5uBG5cpVW3Nh1lNHXnaAOY1X4h7k4gHIhENG0LMCx02Z4kZ5CmObyDwQphT2ThiI57fi157hqFWqQF5PD0wjo7p99gNp69p@n2gZlS6Eui62jYdFZ7zjdmH@V13NSthiepJYZ6CJ6YN9EPTTuZlKBcD6OepIYEBgJ6P0FkZx@33cYUYUgXN7aJ958Rtn0VAnctV3CyMqQCRRXUKmBWcLBybcZvaCYT5otNumzNNSpebKS7GAmVuz4ck0EwLh1h@fSvLfwQBcXB8SvaPH5AOTMSZDuNLQpb4jmvN6dOua7Fu9T09Ls9z/gdOtoGDMasQRfEDo7q1CYUwIri@jbdnPHNbsYOOqeINJMTA6yVsvEVCAt6YkcHnz1DvJyJiQFqaYXrsvaXRgXdNo5lMBefrCX1s1UqXRR5suxOMMJeK/DEj9K7m96llsUEMolhlhugl4385h53a7pk53f0MyO/zuj1Smd8DyImG2ynHn9SvPMviZkd6Po8DLZ/HgabDIx5g@mCQDqyokmU8tN3AdFzb1F0HJMAEjgvmw@ODw9bJ7uO71Yaohr6nWmZbdUBkCzYgoUX9hogSEZK0LxEzUSmezRrbZ77rz/GdwbvFmNctaZS8c4S/IXJ2LVOfnKc1hKiwYFBv4FG4z5utfxRqxvex4ycp34zMra1YztaWCks@DcZ4n6Mbjfs@uhO@GZn@2G670HCSHbi267jR2tXu4KdIzznrvCWAUbOtO1BNLIVQ/@7W@jHXrK2wPlM/lsRragBJAA1Uj1pU82kEnV2V6SD4XrYMrnPcEe7yXNOIhXWielKY4WCb/ImI6yKE3@fFmmYNenNn0ghBiqaD2ynYbE5MBbsPn@yeAlc6OnXNGWo@G8DzxqOj2eA@SANjUKwyRqiG6YMBoWkZKSzhmpkAhyZOnmfaUIO11ILWQQ7Ui@YJwBF2m9l2AAvuJqKMCRZj/mRsQ6UDc4qmPsFMBGY19pwTi5kJk5HMWy8si2ZdCtX4ObsipumUGK9tmVQns8Qou7MxN3D5lIob1YfHxyenIk/4OIbYISTgbcoScdhN25oTapY1JiPYoM7brT7QPBjJvkHvUNpXfZRRIJB@DzBJOHVc2Ot2jzy3OxELoeeNYxvGnhfuxzYwzLvZMBqNINIg07e1wOwXQ8dU@ia1igZVPxpofd2HSdOg58VeYFupRXsPjrOWJAn99Mpox4i01Fotlm7FyyQeCIiQP@NWvkNyDacCs3ONJVu1XJJWY1qEZxE67v7dAXWkHFLk5KJHNUOSy4xf0vH4wPUMSZdr1fU1PNbgtUpp7TbWdFjTApCRq9SWl3LU8inp5JYXLzjV5XauQB2jmstBBhJbVFGZLRUV7Wo4DeeEZR1lLObYSUiUhkQMYsOpQ@ZBTMhZWL5xo1l/fO@4ifQP6XlANMcfUY/3DVpDz3UKnYOZEMsTa6X19R/y4kppXS2tlnklf3NVlnkSWURhi4txooU1UcBUC039EPNjSKNfqAQuNZfxLTOknPQ8noLAkFIXF1NP85OR16@HOMepK8qFopDF3qMbz5QdcvKi99FHz3Z2Vg/I6oHYG3Lg8x7JP7sFIXDjAaGWeUQeHO@T0@MDSr2jpcs8XPUVVYVg6Lx8mfzzB/x18PMSLyxlHuzv5UwFGVIoXFdffnL11Sfvcm8IRM2TRXjAvpDi/AaZsYQBhEdEBDrY1dWlJRVWKJnlytvlSiV3eHyUI4u1WkMo5aEZZOY6bgjqCvlBt6vfsc0nP3j@fNt1XdFy74jbP6yuvnd6o1QCQIVlgsKiQTu4@J9ioscvVd0VFs0OIEirpQ@s0MePqloC6UjydlaVqppAys@3Kjrsn023pqp6Rmo@D3JVlQoQ5EHWXFANoW12ElCjmGo93nt/v9XKGqfAJB7o9P32ccwowPRhOpJ8wcNJOpXVFTUCRecwYFCRGbUNSXRx5JkBVVdW1O1LdeWyItQIGY6ewsVuT0dYGX33wtNReiXC4kfyzJYmKxPwayDvCHo6mgd8mth2Derp9Sh@CVtbW4R/0iKWhpXaKlylEv4LQ0IgpNLcqhBft8fryrBCdtDliy/uDGdCdqcg7okt2HIDz44AgGGl3hKbmTy6lggrrH64U0Ga2mIlm0PWyIvh0h0wBu1ghOLtLYV2nbBD90TSmh0oQxYDjHRnkYMyPN5jsTVcJChytVSpCeSNV6VWQk/cWRpywsWdwsS1s5iRbGjhj8QWY0g5rr2yDQkcM2UF3hvDCT1vkTR5ZaQO6Cm4f2IDPdmAncW3yoauH4rQecvk3ia5S@4RYnDE0tKSoC1vdpfXuze7G4@2TtgFvhe7jma5fcd8IB7HV1HAYDgSC2IIHwc@OnwC@LjwMeFjiJUa8WBJMdyRQ4KRyyoW7eD6RskYNmPuiIQD0vUodTjVXCCyASToAYhVPLPbC5jEiD7Ly8ptK6Rc1ZQcVsiofwfqN1j@TkISvlQia8l3th19ALbMddd8AX@W59h8wQKYR3FpooT3bC1L8S70s3SzcjK40jXyS2@SuPoWje@gN8aU0nvyyJZmPglB5ENOXOK1UsobkaW4LE@G5Ds/Y0WxyjntK83wfE99UVOFVUi2MN1ahg9ey@Tisnn183/64@9@@ep/LM3VPa23/@q/rj7/@lXyd/V3f3P1yb//4Tdw@/0XcEthV598BpCf/evV57@7@uQX7P7Z1c/@DcsM/@1PsRj9M@a09u3HmVoEe/XV77949VVS/cNv5zAyum8mub79BKm/AZFM7aSYiORjMObzr2OCb3/66puIBGp/@E1a/vZjKAMh@58oMgFA/FumMIZz2DfY@M9/9@qrV/@brytsZ6xU8JGvNStxMV/J3Gs1wFQiRL5YU@BfUYqVioJXMR8jeLWmxHggBU5JkuM/uVKToueFdHFZl@QmgrAsx/VLKFdql4zyAiFS5eJSSi8uCIjif16TEjURoi5J9Wa9GdM0ZahyJHsCFtEoH@9MNAKAA2gYFdLKnLrGzLoAQRVp8voLmVNnRsiIAKKkxuvsj/FM6swqrnNiZqh0QZTLVlWUxe1zRfnhWCDV8fa4KvLcfFu6IVd9@pNt3DZXLQq5@Q0gFiGnHYTBaeAtSaJ4Q/QdjwaBdgLL9V5elPP5MYgSLYv2fe2uKCjKw9xzU3p8Zm5Wd9Q9@4M1ua40K7VGvQG3hgo3tVFX4Vap4R8vMzB7xH@NRlNlIERjsdEoqk0fc7Wrv/3H090nD3f3//h/n/3pi1/8yjxzbYqFq3/@6k9f/MOvs6fKUP/66tP/vPr0V1ef/sdOoa@Jm/E@x/nAx0vDiybXIFPWTT@unZnRdUZnrrOXmm5mL6TRdPYZhWE4itjPpkng6vMHZBBXX3589eXnV1/@/dWXP7/6F/j/Jf5/@d/ia/yWmby0zDbhmcyKEGU0mChu3BQ6VUuz24ZGnDI7fHAKOa@dHD4IRrWdw68aGuedDn5y@Y6UK7LTDUinc3K@nUtRvJwrnrmQOnWkIxnPNY4gXavzI41CjqfgUOBfPkEh@1YBVKMztFxTFvQqvjzgUd9322fSVuHg8Oj@7uPDg4LyYPdZ6@nevcenCGs9OHzQun/45PB@YVXmBwISb1uxvXGTOqhZ0ouxLMmQ83qxA2loT5IL7dyOCo01KKOCVvuBZw6kXDUny68XycHxqWKZfUrONzeIbTqmrVmE2qGlBfj2yNSrJ2aHvZSRvKcycr2@T3rUowU8MhmZlsVgeNAD7rVQfAH6wcPzL9IOuz4XArSGS30nx0VEEvDVEUjj21rbGhMHj1UCl9DzADJY4EhfL2GoHrUG/CiMU6CCoGf6RGtDCzX2LX@BaH6f2DR@mUTHnnACH1/MwM0gPOxxdKQDQIcL0HsaDFfY2QtxIPljX2BRxs@PXcuPQo0MNC8wNUsQmCWZsy0eY6CfdMrCArSq62k2qZJOHHY2tV1vDJD6QzClubJx69b6RgStr93aKMMnD2ZIEa/cBNqoLBjUSsqCR7smfh3uA8FF7t5JrkxWz2EzUCC503uZyv4zVlldPToqCAu5A6yibqQ7ScsH9@IyEO3GPEzCXoZlL2a5FDqW1uXK948AeKRZPlIcZyvPs5XTbOUkqVwKAp5oUM9zPcn2uzLzHEZ7Rzx89Oj4UZlcAPgSHkmbb3iXoiwsQA8V6bkZSCWZC@nSoIUd0cIjNwklYQGMjDycCKijx5pN9jYFI4EIwGaVIztykOfpYYDhhefKeMRiREJyoHhKDslXSQmhQeg5TN6UOSM8rERzLBeMmbJSWOiZ86CROAmwlQrZlEmeWK4gPDq8c4oBhL3E@xe7j9332B26lfcUDwXeuU3ku7t7/wh5L@I@lrgQ1g9ygSyS3fuA2ueo/UnU/v04fCSuLkUdIGqPo/YmUXuIYoEW6XrshZGqu8h0kqpKMPuIYUEcaUowB4g5uJcqSjB7d4UokGAydK0h@1rUszeZ1z27AOAutHwCWdpAN@PE5JuOH2iOTiUkhZkEuYANOGK31T27yTp@Aka7zaSjIi1zrEBFIJCV5/X03u7pIXZpPe5B6K8CiWsHce1kAneSxcXQDG0sAaMcpsFWHLPc/tM6t0ZVySZ5j2w2mXlsqMRwWES5CzgEiJizOFmVrDMX8aYzgeCgAslqEhbwtB7JcN0CQatQxKUTvQiTMzYbuZACJaejCv06MyRDx6dBQoQCTFgAPKoH0cgkmq7DSogDNFKZr04JjW1ZBmPO8ShaEBayjVpNbLGxusGqcSunhvN0YxeS5iYcqIsHBSIzekqMLB7h3NbpuJAhieNGzmhKFGm@T2FBisWuvUkqt/paqfGMtSkBqOV6LXAqRu3U@EhwwB4OLMpHCu0WSM/s9tgQiykAYWiBxiMexgBgZO5uJM16gJFByLFFK9u@LP69GB1jI@Hp3B7pbXIlDB0HEeseFkcdEddiPrNjQMWxE4D4i1RIeXXtnC0yWRu4k/xJJxUY6s92lWsZb/KUHyMKRGIti9cE5ItcI2ddl2Fg9JySdz4jjSln/Qd2gG/MLix6m0xZurxyke8UHvE0GnXTxED8Xj2VDP1MN812UdIuttbODQ623s5gwEOlyCBgjczBL0@B/C8XRtPLeRRQE359l4hKFql5bs10IAjmPTjpl2l0Orq4d2bwmdE5N2CgLXMwzKeA7ZlRS6OgisVHbYyrpAZKbnfKKUCpxmoj/8WYrDww8s0CO/NEXis0jf1UZkQYiYidNUEOVryFPubADvVaZ7re8nuQT0iQkhsmpi6c05q3R2Dro5U4CMupb0x8XTKSUSZzdqdAnlVtQqpX2mituwO2MfE9vQQx5wfzd0iIBkzSSj4NIFTm2LUp7MR6gy3yQwtlM0Er@FjL7qFB8VTEcg5gZUlGHTOMZlbHJK9MbjC7gSXheM45MvzZ9p@7Ht8ZAnsB7Zlu@CZrN87zjKIblWTygpeBRY4mxQFk3PEoKU@kBqcnzAbuLqzJRMElOhnuWcLC9IiLxbuDaPs4sZZmhIKls@kNikTlOGtdh48HJ6eZNXyWfE2YXQ2jiIJ8jY09fFnPCwfBNTGcwWP0rrENV5LH8WVpDhnbL2EezsVuStlsQo6yCZTPaZBndYvN1tEL@FWSy7ENk2F4aZ9AdsE2i6Me/pYDhfHtm0NHQKT3PIkpQyaZEXJ@nu7xjSIjBelLkJS0YUnoM0SkFQgBjxCe0XJw/MJKdrWOFpXcB45pw1YBDyzYz2GCtRJJfr4AKwuW2ZqSy8zo1zJHPgS@pJIwC6zjwuhXQywpBEcbZcLPzcrRqsT93E3KGMPTQ7yArOur5czo4qBbb5f2Yp60RTD55ipoWj2/dYQ/LILmtKnljlDqxmYqNRp8cw3a2CrPTHcMcXsjFTA9FWcnHFj6M7MJF6ob5TTiMeWMKzpPDaNDR6iUSWYHlm7rcNDJEZdB35lLSbmwzbNsqSciloTcHbxRSTTByAJmZuy1sUKcoFEntKmnweDFBA@HN/txGUtqMtGDpC/NgeRpTpdK2HMF6LgNuG9CklTPeijii1oe16IWJVVmcZNtb7JBWo8yGmYkOxjj53BShojZDlPnxIhm@HkTUuCNUUlPcwyLZcYT6lgFdoT4theMor@i40McaJkRJ4ZO38HvbjN8ZT7coJ7s/SL5Eh69Hntm13Q0iyRDVWM@bI/JTnrqCtvE6IUvtBd/nVCEPaDeB1N66GX2@qGmljZu3755S725WdrajNaLjnneYmfPEnJC5sHexi0Qy6niPA9OFQgeqVpOuqnFLwyhDrOYouTAwRKeQHJGtmTJKzmSQz4UWVfW2H7PITDtQv4Z2vwQlrLDWSyz15JNdrTqU9yXQOjB3gJfrEMhyYwsilhlYVfQJ@MtUs5N86v8XT9lfY3VkcNCelRUjl66wCaB1ZYMWySz7CuMx6qbzYQtnZNxYvff27qVX1@T0YRoTYt@9DRzqhsf6PL2Z45zi/7AglUr13ByzPtW5CBYVad9w7ok6xn2M8fULQJvMXpl1zfLm/lyeS1fvnl7RbEL26IQOiONTeqAXy1pOjXP3IEvyReX9WalVigqeRFVglAYIfhTIp9P/x3qUTJSiQsYj6uX4reEC2Q3emt5mf/4TjmytL4s9KwBhsIy9DgzsHpNTEGTfejbNGxy0TcktjaQoslGx5M6ksuDTLnO@jhuSbPAmi/L9bVy882KYIfmGHL0wqnEf8/F@16EZBhZ6@U13J4AGUpj9BGIYQEmy6831gsbt/WNdaGSvJADQUPZj@LiEIApEX/GCf2FGRakdzJhb5waboYLL51UFNK7QwP8QRfpTWNxotKJ25mC45W7kSNKbZ7CnjyHvIXE3QGR9LIvC4qi4AtZ39X81FBSq1VRXJFIKO//AQ)

Next answer must not exceed 4881 bytes.

### Explanation

Minkolang is a 3D language that splits its source code into multiple layers stacked on top of one another, like a 3D chess board.  When the IP encounters a space it drops to the next layer, the language documentation describes this as moving along the time dimension.

The IP starts in the top left, encounters the v, which sends it in the down direction until the second line, where it encounters its temporal shift. The layers are delineated by a line that ends in `$$$`. So I inserted a `$$$` line, and a simple Minkolang answer.

```
$$$

>"gnalokniM"OOOOOOOOO.
```

Since we entered the time shift on the second line, the minkolang answer begins two lines down from the `$$$`, where `>` catches the IP and sends it to the right, through the appropriate code to answer. But of course this caused Somme headaches.

Ultimately, I ended up adding a buch of characters to the first line of Minkolang’s second layer to satisfy Somme, and a few more characters to the $$$ line so that I could avoid the flack sensitive tokens. This is final result of that debugging.

```
& I8 H I  d      $$$
a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP<
>"gnalokniM"OOOOOOOOO.
```

Good Luck!

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6946 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M eliF MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 7066 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a7a 667a 7a7a  /opfzzfzzfzzfzzz
00000060: 667a 7a66 7a66 7a66 6666 7a66 667a 7a7a  fzzfzfzfffzffzzz
00000070: 7a7a 6666 7a66 7a7a 7a66 667a 667a 7a7a  zzffzfzzzffzfzzz
00000080: 667a 667a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a7a 7a66 7a66  fzfzfzzfzfzzzfzf
00000090: 7a66 7a7a 667a 667a 6666 667a 7a66 7a66  zfzzfzfzfffzzfzf
000000a0: 7a7a 7a66 7a66 6666 66e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  zzzfzffff.......
000000b0: a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1  ................
000000c0: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086  ................
000000d0: e2a1 865c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  ...\. /+ #\. bas
000000e0: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
000000f0: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000100: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000110: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
00000130: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
00000140: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
00000150: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
00000160: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
00000170: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000180: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000190: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
000001a0: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
000001b0: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
000001c0: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
000001d0: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
000001e0: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
000001f0: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000200: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000210: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
00000220: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
00000230: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
00000240: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
00000250: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
00000260: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
00000270: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000280: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000290: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
000002a0: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
000002c0: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000300: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000320: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
00000330: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
00000340: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000350: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
00000360: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000370: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000380: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000390: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
000003a0: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
000003b0: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
000003c0: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
000003e0: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
000003f0: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000400: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000410: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
00000420: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
00000440: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
00000450: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
00000470: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000480: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
000004a0: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
000004b0: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
000004c0: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
000004d0: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000500: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000510: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
00000560: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
00000570: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000580: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000590: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005a0: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2026 2049 3820 4820   <>"v"@. & I8 H 
000005b0: 4920 2064 2020 2020 2020 2424 240a 6126  I  d      $$$.a&
000005c0: 3867 2633 6734 6736 5239 5050 5050 5050  8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP
000005d0: 3c0a 3e22 676e 616c 6f6b 6e69 4d22 4f4f  <.>"gnalokniM"OO
000005e0: 4f4f 4f4f 4f4f 4f2e 0a20 402c 2246 222c  OOOOOOO.. @,"F",
000005f0: 2275 222c 226e 222c 2263 222c 2274 222c  "u","n","c","t",
00000600: 226f 222c 2269 222c 2264 223c 3e20 7265  "o","i","d"<> re
00000610: 6420 646f 776e 2074 776f 2072 6564 206c  d down two red l
00000620: 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075  eft one yellow u
00000630: 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c  p green down yel
00000640: 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77  low up green dow
00000650: 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074 6872 6565 2072  n red up three r
00000660: 6564 2072 6967 6874 2074 776f 2079 656c  ed right two yel
00000670: 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  low down yellow 
00000680: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067  down blue left g
00000690: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 646f  reen down red do
000006a0: 776e 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f  wn one yellow do
000006b0: 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265  wn blue left gre
000006c0: 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 646f 776e  en down red down
000006d0: 2074 776f 2072 6564 206c 6566 7420 6f6e   two red left on
000006e0: 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 7965 6c6c  e yellow up yell
000006f0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
00000700: 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564  t green down red
00000710: 206c 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7265 6420 646f   left one red do
00000720: 776e 2074 6872 6565 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  wn three yellow 
00000730: 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  down yellow down
00000740: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e   blue left green
00000750: 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074 776f   down red up two
00000760: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000770: 6f77 2075 7020 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  ow up yellow dow
00000780: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 7265 6420  n blue left red 
00000790: 7570 2074 6872 6565 2072 6564 2072 6967  up three red rig
000007a0: 6874 2074 776f 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f  ht two yellow do
000007b0: 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062  wn yellow down b
000007c0: 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2030 3030 3131 3130  lue left 0001110
000007d0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
000007e0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030 3030  0001000001010000
000007f0: 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100000000010001
00000800: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
00000810: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030 3030  0001000001010000
00000820: 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0100000100010000
00000830: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030  0100010001000000
00000840: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000100000100
00000850: 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100011000010001
00000860: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130  0001000001000110
00000870: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
00000880: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000100000100
00000890: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
000008a0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000100000100
000008b0: 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100000000010001
000008c0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0000010001000100
000008d0: 3030 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3130 3030  0000011000011000
000008e0: 3030 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3030  0011000001001100
000008f0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031  0001000100010001
00000900: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130  0001000000100110
00000910: 3131 3130 3030 3030 3031 3130 3031 3131  1110000001100111
00000920: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3131 3030 3030 3030  1000110011000000
00000930: 3031 3030 3131 3130 3031 3131 3130 3030  0100111001111000
00000940: 3031 3130 3131 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0110111000001000
00000950: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
00000960: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
00000970: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
00000980: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030 3031 3130  0000100011000110
00000990: 3131 3131 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031  1111000100010001
000009a0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3031 3030 3030  0000010001010000
000009b0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  1000000010001000
000009c0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
000009d0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
000009e0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
000009f0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 300a 3031 2026  00000100110.01 &
00000a00: 2026 2620 2626 2620 2020 2020 2620 7b7d   && &&&     & {}
00000a10: 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372 6168  ]........laocrah
00000a20: 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  C...............
00000a30: e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2 86a8  ................
00000a40: c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3 9fe2  ................
00000a50: 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690 e289  ................
00000a60: a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286 92e2  ................
00000a70: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a80: e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a90: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1  ................
00000aa0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692 e286  ................
00000ab0: a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000ac0: 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000ad0: c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82 e286  ................
00000ae0: a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000af0: e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c 82e2  ................
00000b00: 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000b10: c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80  ................
00000b20: c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2 96b2  ................
00000b30: e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2 a1ce  ................
00000b40: b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000b50: b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2 bb2b  ...............+
00000b60: 5b2d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d  [-++++[-<+++++>]
00000b70: 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  <[-<++++++<+++++
00000b80: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b  <+++++>>>]<<<+++
00000b90: 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d  ++++.>-.>---.<<-
00000ba0: 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d  ----.++++++++.--
00000bb0: 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e  ---.>--.>---.<+.
00000bc0: 3e3e 3e5d 2828 2928 2928 2928 2928 2929  >>>](()()()()())
00000bd0: 3c3e 2828 2928 2929 3c3e 7b28 7b7d 5b28  <>(()())<>{({}[(
00000be0: 295d 293c 3e28 7b28 7b7d 2928 7b7d 5b28  )])<>({({})({}[(
00000bf0: 295d 297d 7b7d 293c 3e7d 3c3e 2828 297b  )])}{})<>}<>((){
00000c00: 5b28 295d 283c 7b7d 2828 2828 2828 2828  [()](<{}((((((((
00000c10: 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b  ((()()()){}){}){
00000c20: 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829  }){}()){})((()()
00000c30: 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d  ()()){}){})[(([]
00000c40: 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28  []){}){}()])([](
00000c50: 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b  )){})[]())(([[][
00000c60: 5d28 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d  ]()]([]()((((([]
00000c70: 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d  [][])){}{})[]){}
00000c80: 2929 295b 5d28 2929 3e29 7d7b 7d29 7b7b  )))[]())>)}{}){{
00000c90: 7d28 3c28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  }(<(((((((((((((
00000ca0: 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  (()()()){}){}){}
00000cb0: 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928  ){}()){})((()()(
00000cc0: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b  )()){}){})[(([][
00000cd0: 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829  ]){}){}()])([]()
00000ce0: 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 295b 5b5d 2829 2829  ){})[]())[[]()()
00000cf0: 2829 5d29 5b5d 295b 5b5d 2829 2829 2829  ()])[])[[]()()()
00000d00: 2829 5d29 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 5b28 295d 2928  ()])[][][][()])(
00000d10: 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 2829  (((((()()()){}()
00000d20: 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 2928 295d  ){}){}){})[()()]
00000d30: 293e 297d 7b7d 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922  )>)}{}({ -}_=")"
00000d40: 3b78 2d2d 3f79 0a20 3d79 3b79 3d22 7972  ;x--?y. =y;y="yr
00000d50: 7275 4322 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169  ruC";(!)=seq;mai
00000d60: 6e3d 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 696e 2070  n=let b!_=""in p
00000d70: 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574  utStr$(""!"snret
00000d80: 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229 2b2b 792d 2d3f  taPgnaB+")++y--?
00000d90: 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 220a 2d2d 4e27 5a69  "lleksaH".--N'Zi
00000da0: 2854 6a69 383d 402f 426d 5532 295b 2d5d  (Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]
00000db0: 3c3e 5c5b 5c3c 3e5c 5c2f 3c3e 5c2f 5c5b  <>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[
00000dc0: 2f5c 2f5c 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c  /\/\<><><>\[/\/\
00000dd0: 2f3c 3e5c 2f2f 5c2f 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e  /<>\//\/<><><><>
00000de0: 3c3e 5c5c 5d2f 5c2f 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f 5c5d  <>\\]/\//\//\/\]
00000df0: 2f5c 2f5c 5c2e 2f5d 732a 2f2f 2fe2 8899  /\/\\./]s*///...
00000e00: 5341 564e 4143 efbd 90f0 9f92 ac69 6a6f  SAVNAC.......ijo
00000e10: 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e a1f0 9f98 ad45 6d6f  me...........Emo
00000e20: 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f 6ef0 9f98 b2e2 8faa  tinomicon.......
00000e30: e28f ace2 8fa9 402c 6b61 2238 392d 6567  ......@,ka"89-eg
00000e40: 6e75 6665 6e55 7373 7373 7361 6161 6161  nufenUsssssaaaaa
00000e50: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 7061 6565 6565  eeeeeeeeeepaeeee
00000e60: 6565 6565 6565 6369 7361 6565 6565 6565  eeeeeecisaeeeeee
00000e70: 656a 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6565  ejiiiiiiiijeeeee
00000e80: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 656a 7a61  eeeeeeeeeeeeejza
00000e90: 6369 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65  ciiiiiiiiiiiiije
00000ea0: 6565 6163 6565 6163 6577 7575 7577 6565  eeaceeacewuuuwee
00000eb0: 6a69 6969 696a 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969  jiiiijiiiiiiiiii
00000ec0: 696a 6565 6561 6161 616b 6565 6161 6161  ijeeeaaaakeeaaaa
00000ed0: 7776 77e2 a080 e2a0 96e2 a097 e2a0 8ee2  wvw.............
00000ee0: a28e e2a2 a6e2 a2a6 e2a0 ae22            ..........."
```

Answer (score 3):

## 6. [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 146 bytes

```
void main(){//\
/*;ooo"><>"
printf("C")/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
J'zvSfN0cb&)}kf ;K-+ ,+;q,+;60d}[}q(-6+:puupd"*///SmiVZZ⎚laocrahC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxbsIwGIX3/wosloc0cUh@YGCokRc6tRILUgfKYuJEWE1ik9hpRJUr9AA9Xi@ShgWGb/ie3nsn2Z7HMZOOCNLpKs2MygH6Xt2NiGAFMBlJ2kdovLPepa6/DVHlHda@LMlKBEuA292jMI6d0YpUUtdh9I14BGTcGEPFRlCwja5dEdItjZChrqxpHGmdSie04fSFpl@NdjkyhnxABq9P125f7BbZKYiGz4LwtyQm85hfJtYLNXwMlzBZx8/We6soQ8TZvtLvs8Ph7@e3lCZr5Hn7Dw)

Prints **miV** in Vim **laocrahC** in [Charcoal](https://tio.run/##DcMxDoIwFADQnSuwNB0UivCdGKxhwUkTFxIHdKmthEagUAsmml7BA3g8L1J5yeM101yxxrlJSYFaJrsgfANcPCBUKYWzbYa9XsvOVAHOcQgEZNsrbdDDiGQuFcU7nDy1NDcgBKgF4u2Xr6mojmt@XYT2XiF6iCO0iugwT9fCnu0QxGm06cexF5gAgF@08uSX5e/zbZjimtW5c38), **C** in [C](https://tio.run/##DcMxDoIwFADQnSuwNB0UivCZGKxhwUkTFxIHdMFWtBFoqQUTTa/gATyeF6m@5LGYtXV/cW6SgqOuFn0QvgCOHhAqpcT5Ksee0qI3TYALHAIB0SmpDbobnvwLSfEaJw8tzBkIAWqBeJv5cyqbXcpOs9DeGkS3cYQWER3@s5Tbgx2COIuWahwVxwQA/LITe7@qvu9PW0um62vh3A8), **><>** in [><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0OzWl8/hktfyzo/P1/JzsZOiaugKDOvJE1DyVlJU19LPzO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrZVclPTKizJLUvW1tPSta/W1uLzUq8qC0/wMkpPUNGuz0xSsvXW1FXS0rQuB2MwgpTa6tlBD10zbqqC0tCBFSUtfX186ODczTDoq6lHfrJzE/OSixAzn//8B), **emmoS** in [Somme](https://tio.run/##DcMxDoIwFADQnSuwNB0UivCdGKxhwUkTFxIHdEEKsdHSUgomml7BA3g8L1J5yRukEI1zk@QMiYp3QfgGuHhAqJQSZ9sMe0rzzrQBznEIBLhQUhs0GJbMuaR4h5On5qYBQoBaIN5@@ZqK9riur4vQ3ltED3GEVhHt5@ma2bPtgziNNmocFcMEAPxC8JNflr/P91HJWle33Lk/), and **D** in [D](https://tio.run/##S/n/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0OzWl8/hktfyzo/P1/JzsZOiaugKDOvJE1DyVlJU19LPzO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrZVclPTKizJLUvW1tPSta/W1uLzUq8qC0/wMkpPUNGuz0xSsvXW1FXS0rQuB2MwgpTa6tlBD10zbqqC0tCBFSUtfX186ODczTDoq6lHfrJzE/OSixAzn//8B)

Next answer cannot exceed 189 bytes (130% * 146).

#### Hexdump

The code contains unprintables, here's a hexdump:

```
00000000: 766f 6964 206d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a  void main(){//\.
00000010: 2f2a 3b6f 6f6f 223e 3c3e 220a 7072 696e  /*;ooo"><>".prin
00000020: 7466 2822 4322 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274  tf("C")/*/import
00000030: 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77   std.stdio;"D".w
00000040: 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 0a4a 277a  rite/**/;}/*.J'z
00000050: 7653 664e 3063 6226 297d 6b66 203b 4b2d  vSfN0cb&)}kf ;K-
00000060: 2b20 2c2b 3b71 2c2b 3b36 3064 7d5b 7d71  + ,+;q,+;60d}[}q
00000070: 282d 362b 3a70 7575 7064 222a 2f2f 2f1b  (-6+:puupd"*///.
00000080: 536d 6956 1b5a 5ae2 8e9a 6c61 6f63 7261  SmiV.ZZ...laocra
00000090: 6843                                     hC
```

Answer (score 3):

## 7. [Objective-C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Objective-C.html), 177 bytes

```
void main(){//\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
>.:<RaNs^rp/nWj"<AK*///⎚laocrahC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBCoJAGEb3XsGNTBsd0H@fIpStChISCiSScRzrl5yRcbBFdIUO0PG6yOSyxQfv8T5Vd4IbnETIwyvn1k4KG69nKP3gCXB2gLpFj0e3LGOlFEmTlDiLRrQohVeQmbGdzauqfL3NquqvhWJCw0VX5/NLyAZbZ9AoTeuTjBQBUMB@UNp4o2mieahisiHRQ6MRQCnEL6BOGi2TA9uPFz2APHUkWe0oAHzfnztTXLNbZu0P) (Can  be switched to every compatible language but Vim)

[Try it online (Vim)!](https://tio.run/##TYxBasMwEEX3ukI2QoWQCKKhWdZG0DqrFBqooYUQahRLJhNsyciyayi9Qg/Q4/UirrJpuhiY9/@bOaruNE2lClTSARtROm0IGUf9R1TO14REoqvuGro@tH0QYbwcgjYD2L6u6VrObwm5vLsK0zQ41LRRaBfLD4ADAT7LG3yZ7feJc47JVDJyo02F1tCcxR2rSLQodg/brCj@dSszYCjN@biLlrEaK9J6tKFasIzlS@CATet8oF3QIg66hG2YePcYDHAOySdwIsVd@qyeujffgn09s/T@kQPAz9d3rVzp1Sn7BQ)

Contains two unprintables (0x1B) surrounding the `SmiV` portion.

Prints **C-evitcejbO** in Objective-C, while maintaining everything else.

Hex dump:

```
00000000: 766f 6964 206d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a  void main(){//\.
00000010: 2f2a 1b53 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 223e  /*.SmiV.ZZ;ooo">
00000020: 3c3e 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 220a  <>".#define S"".
00000030: 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a  #ifdef __OBJC__.
00000040: 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 2d65 7669 7463  #define S"-evitc
00000050: 656a 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966 0a70 7269  ejbO".#endif.pri
00000060: 6e74 6628 2243 2253 292f 2a2f 696d 706f  ntf("C"S)/*/impo
00000070: 7274 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422  rt std.stdio;"D"
00000080: 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 0a3e  .write/**/;}/*.>
00000090: 2e3a 3c52 614e 735e 7270 2f6e 576a 223c  .:<RaNs^rp/nWj"<
000000a0: 414b 2a2f 2f2f e28e 9a6c 616f 6372 6168  AK*///...laocrah
000000b0: 43                                       C
```

Next answer cannot exceed **230** bytes.

Uses an Objective-C specific macro, `__OBJC__` and string concatenation to print `-evitcejbO` only when run in Objective-C. Moved vim code to the top (so no other code could interfere), and deleted some junk at the bottom to conform with the byte count rules.

This works in both gcc and tcc.

Answer (score 3):

## 8. [Befunge-98](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 194 bytes

```
void main(){//\
/*SmiVZZ;ooo"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*
>"Befunge-98"9k,@
 ,wVkk_,xeWvl>~u{A*///⎚laocrahC
```

Prints `D` in [D](https://tio.run/##TYrBasJAFEX38wtuhucmDtG3bUgJ1bhy4yJgIRSG1HlTnzEzEscohPYT/AA/rz@SZtnFhXM41wxD59nIpmIXzXrED4FqUjS8m5Rl6r2H7DUDMTVk2ZEsYGS2o0mtt6tNrvW/NqeOw56On9vxRc6wFeeWXbAR5FDMUCE3Z98GeQlmMY59CmtY3FoOhEph@o1KZLAie3VfNE9eIKnjNyHj266udXyn9@6U/Vz7pULE38fzVPl9Wx3yYfgD), `emmoS` in [Somme](https://tio.run/##TYpBqsIwFEXn2YKT8JxoqL6pUilqHTlxUPCDfAjVvuizJpEaqyDfJbgAl/c3Ujt0cOEczr14a6lpas@FtDm7Xv@B@CtQdTLL685mE3vvIZkkILoFGXYkM2iZTWtS69V8mWr91QZUc9jRcbtqX@QKNuJcsQumBylkfVTI9uyrIC@hGLZjH8MChreKA6FSGP@hEgnMyVzdngbjEYzLaCpkdFuXpY7u9FOfkuf1MVOI@P96n3K/q/JD2jQf), `><>` in [><>](https://tio.run/##TYoxCsJAEEX7vYLNMja6RKdVIkGNlY1FQEGEJZpZHWN2Ja5RED2CB/B4XiSmtPjwHu8bvhzqunKcySJl2@k@EDcCVSspeNlar0PnHESjCEQ7I8OWZAINs2lMar2YzmOt/1qPKvY7Om4XzYtsxkacS7bedCCGpIsKuTi70suLz/rN2IUwg/6tZE@oFIZPVCKCKZmr3VNvOIBhHoyFDG7LPNfBnVbVKXpdHxOFiN/355S6XZke4rr@AQ), `C` in [C](https://tio.run/##TYpBisJAEEX3fQU3Tc1Gm8TajkSCmlnNxkXAARGa2KnWmphuiW0UZOYIHsDjeZGYpYsP7/G@iXfGdF3ruZR1wW44uiFuBKpBXvNqsF4n3ntIpymIj5IsO5I59My2N6n1cvGdaf3WYmo5GPrdLvsXuZKtODbsgh1CBvkIFXJ99E2Qp1CO@7FP4AvGl4YDoVKY/KESKSzInt2O4sknTKpoJmR0WVWVjq700x7S//NtrhDxeX8cCm@aYp913Qs), `laocrahC` in [Charcoal](https://tio.run/##TYrBasJAFEX38wtuhteNDtG3VVKCGlfduAhYkMIwJm/qM8mMTMdYkPoJfoCf1x9Js@ziwjmcWx5NKL1p@r7zXMnWsBtPbogfAtWoaHk32u9T7z1krxmIl4osO5IFDMx2MKn1dv2Wa/2vTanjWNLpsB1e5Cq24hzYRTuGHIoJKuT27EOUX7GaDWOfwgZm18CRUClMf1CJDNZkL@6Tpos5LOpkKWRy3dW1Tr7pvWuy@@W2Uoj4@3g2xpfBHPO@/wM), `miV` in [Vim](https://tio.run/##TYxBasMwEEX3ukI2QoWQCNtDs2pwEW3cVTdZGFIIAaNYcjO1LRlbdgyhPUIP0OP1Iq66abr4MG/ezD/K7jRNuXRU0AHrKLdKk3FUf0DFfEU80LC77mzvmt5FbvRvoPQApq8quhLzW/JbddXTNFhUtJZoFssLwIEAn6U17mb7fWytZeJeMHKjdIFG05T5GQtPNMu2m@cky/65UA/ocv123PorbRQWpGnRuGLBEpYugQPWjW0d7ZyKfNDG7IlF5xadBs4hfgdOBNvoojevOlzfsXUZPBAanHdlmQWjfhkq8dFfHjkAfH9@VdLmrTwlPw), `C-evitcejbO` in [Objective-C](https://tio.run/##TYpBisJAEEX3fQU3TbnRJrG2SiSMxpUbFwEHRGhip9opY7ol08YBGY/gATyeF8lkOYsP7/G@P5zIBG4pNvHRmK5rPZeyLtiNxnfEvUA1yGveDna7xHsP6TwFMSzJsiOZQ89se5Nab5brTOt/LaaWg6HTYdO/yJVsxaVhF@wIMsjHqJDri2@C/A7lpB/7BFYwuTUcCJXC5BeVSGFJ9uqOFM@mMKuiDyGj27aqdPRDn@05fVzvC4WI7@frXHjTFF9Z1/0B), `89-egnufeB` in [Befunge-98](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//8vy89MUchNzMzT0KzW14/h0teSDs7NDJOOirLOz89XsrOxU@JSTklNy8xLVQhWArIz04A8hfh4fycv5/h4JDnd1LLMkuTUrCR/oKrUvJTMNK6Cosy8kjQNJWelYE19Lf3M3IL8ohKF4pIUPSDOzLdWclHSKy/KLEnV19LSt67V1@KyU3KCO1LJMlvHgUtBpzwsOztepyI1vCzHrq602lFLX1//Ud@snMT85KLEDOf//wE), and `a partridge` in [A Pear Tree](https://tio.run/##TYrBasJAFEX38wtuhteNDolvq6QENV114yKgIIVhat7oa8xMmI6xIPoJ/YB@Xn8kZuniwjmca9KWTEhjIOr7znMlG8NuPLkifghUo7LhzWi3y7z3kL/mIF4qsuxIljAw28Gk1uvVe6H1U0up47inr8/18CJXsRVtYBftGAooJ6iQm9aHKL9jNR3GPoM3mF4CR0KlMLuhEjmsyJ7dgdL5DOZ1shAyuWzqWic/tO1O@f18XSpE/P/9Oxm/D@ZY9P0D)

Next answer cannot exceed **252** bytes.

#### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 206d 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a  void main(){//\.
00000010: 2f2a 1b53 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 223e  /*.SmiV.ZZ;ooo">
00000020: 3c3e 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 220a  <>".#define S"".
00000030: 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a  #ifdef __OBJC__.
00000040: 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 2d65 7669 7463  #define S"-evitc
00000050: 656a 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966 0a70 7269  ejbO".#endif.pri
00000060: 6e74 6628 2243 2253 292f 2a2f 696d 706f  ntf("C"S)/*/impo
00000070: 7274 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422  rt std.stdio;"D"
00000080: 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 0a3e  .write/**/;}/*.>
00000090: 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3822 396b 2c40  "Befunge-98"9k,@
000000a0: 0a20 2c77 566b 6b5f 2c78 6557 766c 3e7e  . ,wVkk_,xeWvl>~
000000b0: 757b 412a 2f2f 2fe2 8e9a 6c61 6f63 7261  u{A*///...laocra
000000c0: 6843                                     hC
```

Comment: Please add the next question byte limit as in the above answers. Also, please list what it prints in each language.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix done

Comment: Wassup with the partridge? Nice touch!

Comment: @FreezePhoenix A Pear Tree is a trivial derivative of Perl created by User:ais523 in 2016, mostly as a joke. [...] The semantics are identical to Perl, except [...] Additionally, before running the program, the source code is potentially rotated [...] The point that becomes the new start of the program is determined by checking all substrings of the program to see if they have a CRC-32 of zero. [...] If there are no appropriate substrings, the interpreter prints a partridge and exits, rather than running the program. -- The Esolangs page on A Pear Tree.

Comment: Yes, but it was never one of the languages listed. Oh, are you making a joke on listing the languages

Comment: @FreezePhoenix r/woooosh

Comment: Good job! I was trying to find a way to squeeze Befunge in there, but that `0/0` kept messing with me!

Comment: @Zachary The trick is to use Befunge-98 instead of Befunge-93.

Comment: Well, I found one that doesn't ask!

Answer (score 3):

## 20. zsh, 756 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*/main(){//\
 /+ #\
 [ "$(basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)")" = "bash" ] && echo hsab || echo hsz<<'EOF' #>>
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@(
n4j\Ys`9)|bF4I*`p|*///]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";main=putStr"lleksaH"-- *///@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTpbcttIkt/CFeanDKoNQAQIUrJliSI51tPWrm0pLHePxxTNBoECCQsPBh4SZVkTMReYA@wB9gb7vRFzlLmIN7MeIPhwd8fu0hZZVfmszKzMSpAjJ5t8/14jh55HHELHTjGOnTckT2A2TcL7cZjkJKdZTiZOGtMsI6N78i6gJ1/pl5tkpNTIcRKGzjSjRD1OPKoSJ/aIepiOi4jGeaaSjLp5kMQZ8ZOUjGie05TQ2ZSmAY1dqiiuk5MecYFWCWNiZWzI3hojn9TIEfWLeEyt/R0lTwp3QqZpAIwVEB345D4piIO6S4EmiZwbSrIipbiLKPEC/56ABo3pPckSkk9AXj6h90BCSRC7YeFRDwa4SMIgvlGoO0mIFRN1s6WCapy2srqNq16SLa7u4GqWRBG1/GCGMGV6n0@SeGdp9c3hu1c/H746HZ6/Ozn92G0pR3/9cHrVVTf1O5dYbge3bqgK7JoZjoROPC6cMdWNB2WDyVNrZHORS4NstkyyyTiBh8BhqrIxAt8CQ6ZxLynyaZELBmJz31J620NfuDn1JO/ldSsOlQ2w9BPiRlPC2RAJJE@frgcA1QFaNFY2ON@/pEk8FlgN8prOvCKatgE6m3lEKucHysaSecAs@tJm6y0D7CPUtcj1r5s6BhFnYlz/is5kruvJWHnEaJnk@TRr2/Y4yCfFqOEmkf0hvT/PL2LwOrXz9D7IEzmm1I6cDGLVvkudKURrBhykJ4iKJ0IlKlOBjZU57AQAXuQRKy1iFsdV4BWGAiCkBZwjO5nmNgsO/t5IRysEvU4P0GUkMQo/yCbsDUN6Gf8YsBmWa@Wua4@C2IbP9cocw5l2EycsScS8HKwT8EsQAf5tEJVnFcaNHEKgZ3v01o6LMCTbvactjA30iwBXeVyMvmBWuKUWqjtG/WYkKRddztdKqmtMBLBs2EuLVcZlstiTexqVK8wW/mgUrGxpnmKWqBgJjLk@30juBCGeqPrOfpX@DMLl5OKKHF@8JX4Q0orDeJqoIr9KwjU@HSchc2uWunK8zvg/x9UNTu/ZhFhWlnvd/T0YFALhx3t8sWKZF1aU@4GNb8BBLv6Yw@7vcCiXd1d4jFIniP3CvSlZyIX5aIXoQ/o7m87TH2ya8bT80FmUN3FA3hGOXjtCHrEOFwghdar8Y4Xpaye7oWHIDjGwYpMVpK@M/mtJrrBM5BPtOu5MU9pjWb6nlSUC0zQWSBeTVzKlsa4hhmY0Uup4utFm9LqLNS9JPd01et2dbay1fNZpbb/AmUtiKNhBrHV6TzUaQln2tae1B470eKCZNPa6mgb5UyrUsZkqHRvVuo6v40uWM9s41Fh1FklUEKjXcR/yJgkg47Js@WTQ/3B@MUD8d3SWwwUgu4MaHxVwaUBl6MylUCkwj7P61Gvt7PyZD7daO3ar2eaT@rOmYfDi1UBmtZosEzhTFSwUqOq3DLhpmf3ZJvCytYppmSLtMtNj5QYf2bXa3NC8mn//fpsEHrG3rAfLIrXJ@ycfrZfk8vPkb3/7@PJl84Q0T9TJLV/8NCH1j8@J@vbJW0JDsP/bi2NydXFCaXq2@ViHV38LikUQQ4G27WuF2HVSg48@1FIdIojGTkRxjJ7ECwYBUyeuvblp0xlUekMlXRlxA8xwrKpMMmdEvn2Tk6@djnZ6caaRWq@ntOo2CrK3/jQeu6@i4Jc/ffp0kCSJGiav1IM/d5s/XT1ptWChw8qHUvOoD44iVyqMAx9mZDi8OPq34@GwArPobZC79MvoArAgTAJfWFaHonJl2Ft2EE2TNCdw7hrwFyQHUOsad2mQU3tryz54tLc6HQWOxQf1oPZ1qB6p5svedv2AwMUIXoM@uT2oHezdmC/ut62Dl6ZJOoDfqyaW2udPzear2ufh5jOr16r3zPL1UlfiZ1@u/5r9um98G509O9/6dfptC@ww@Nc//uOf//2vv/9X6CRu6kyO//mfzCdWBz/qvUFHDuudynuvB5COANQbPQv@W1aj07Hw1ahLAJ/2LAkH1F5Pn78M/Gc8PJb/@UxCSlhf1/uD/kDiDAyYciD7BCiCAcDWGWtcAArAYViIawjsB2I9DrsQOgcYeF2491zlqRqG9CZzXqsQ0miZl@aNo@7tW3QcFz6Nf1a/@2kSka9hMCLclVuKcCmG6e4zxe@GTjTyHBK3WQ6KTS0dlTlI8bojDeP0eub7@KfVfV1rsKs6HCvNqI@0OYiPtcaXBE6Gr58ZmN7OIDX1eWYzNX4UYcCLJAyqF2VtYChuF25pkJeyDGq@vm@enJ69OfxwemJabw8/Dv9ydP7hCteGb0/fDt@c/nL6xmwaPGh1vqPGaPcZtBkgT3cbkpfuGXW34YdFNtENc6S9tGGLHmVYsNcsT4OprnU1w4DGCOq6FQbQUcz2dkkUxEHkhIRGRejk2M8sNUOQHbCNKDunuyS9yciEptTEhHkXQKnANczyYNQQ2Ztg/RR0HpNRMc44E8D1EprFGmchOGCzA6lj5IzCexJjUoUOB1IuHFagmDdEDDSh4RQE5hOBgQLySZARZwQ7dFhvYRIoXySisv1x0f6Q60kCVQaSAnxE9yKhw2LMGcDtECINTqwiwye7zxQWW6xpSZIwEwFGpk6aB06oKEyTSmHjkQXyiQ9dAOxqnDoRJEJfBltEowTKTJf034Eqg63d5893dsVqf/v5bhv@6qCGLmiNAeCKseLRsBwrKR0HeJXPAOFBO7/U2qQ5azWbJtGuziuT449s0myenZnKhnaCU5SNeJfz8cm5HAPSoaRhHI4qJEeS5FGBC8iYCz8@g8UzB@oyYFxUJ5@qk6vq5LKcQBuDuZumaZLqUTY2mOUw2n319P37i/dt8gDLj/BR7vlJ@qgaygZ4qEFnQa63DM5kTPMhOmKIBVdHTjgAJYWFSwZ9tNhgwHpAhgIRgNtqCz00KGJukWN4FTEvJp5gooHgJT6k3iUtXM2LNGb8ltS5w6sKqhMmoMySlsrGJFi3KtjpAO10yJ5B6iRMFOX96asrDCD0Evcvuo@9H7F3cCv3FA8F7twB0r0@fHOGtA/SxzpnwvxgmKRGDt8A6JiDjhdBx29k@Ohc3Bx0gqAjDjpaBB0hiAWakPUhLYSo10h0ORdVQo4RwoJYSCohJwg5OZ8LKiFHrxURSJAMk/CWDqPES6M9ZvU0MmF5DDtfALZ20cyYmLIgznIndqmOqJBJkArIgEKarZ9GA@b4hTU6HpSOElLWaIGCgCEbr/P00eHVKbq0Lz0I/jKJnJ3I2eUC7LIKk6sVXMkBoxzS4FDGLNf/qs@1sW2yR34iewOmHjsqch1KJzcBXwEkZiyO1iU7zER864whGMgkVUnKBt7VEQ3rFjBqwhALJloRkjNuG6kQAznPTxXadeVIFnFG8xIJGQRQAFLomsXJJI7rQiXEAypE1rtLTKUuT0EZKOS@rygb1U01S10inO6yqdzl0nFe3uxGud2SAmXxoEBgRU6LockTznVdjguDPBVKrkgqBTlZRqEgSbbbv8WVa/1DrjJj7cGVfjxM0iEYFaN26XyUMCAvpiHlJ4WOTTIJxhN2xCQGADwnd3jEwxkAiMHNjahVCzA0CDlWtKr7q8J/kmAJFcznuV3IHXAhDCyDiLmHxZGvYi3mmR0DSsZODuwf5kzaze0ZKzJVHbiRskUjmQz0fzZVEnq/ZalMAkyis53JmoB0wjRG1XQVAobPMbnzGarEXLUf6AG2CcZQ9PaYsHl55Sz/UHjINCrctHAQ/1eeKo9@xU2rLir3xWrt2uBg9XYFAhZqCYWAVKhDIF0B@v9fGC2XcxFQC3b9IxFVFql1Zq04EBhzDy7aZRk8P13cOivwyulcGzCwlzUQZlOATgKxUxFUkr3Yo5xCT92cvfDb8wWrK8UK@0lIlR8o@dsM/XUsf8h0HvtzngJRsJDGWkAHLX4HX1KgQ9PhF9cdZhPoJ3Q3gUKGrQunDNfdEVh9DEsD4XhumwAf5goebbLmdgroVdEBtHqt3eFOMmUXkyx1WxBzWb7@hoRggJS75GkAVw0O3V6CLtQb3FFWhMibMdrCj@3qHRoEL0UspwBS1mT0scMYVGUs0hrkCdMbSEqKT5yiQl/d/yxJ@c0QyE3UZ3nje2zfmOcZxliMDPKZj4HEEElxCh23PCXthdbg6pLpwM2FM4NYWKLL415FNJdPnGSfTMX1caGWVpiCpqvtDbJE4Zi1fgSXh5PjrCq@ir6trFZDEVHQr7GzFwNBWkzzH8RwBY7Ru80uXGUfx8vSGjR2X8I@nLPd06vdhCG6CeTPcZCmuc@ytfgKr0s0jV2YPC@d@wS6C3ZZvJsEIWXM@PUtpneA5E5SnQlDIoMhcnre7vGLIkMF7pvQlIygJNwwgJAKiADHFd7R8mX5uLparUVR0X6OgwiuCvjAgn2Bm2@3SPmlKVQWHLOaolUy@g@JhQ2BrpyUxApzXCG@x2ZNIRjaaxP@tKwtqhK387gcYwwvH3ETSXea7crp4kvPf5/b53XcaqDysyZIas6en@FX4bCdEQ2TO@S6uzfnKg7fWoV299sr6Y4BXuzOGSyn4mrCgdJfySacqeu15xGPLaecuLw1FI8aYdImlRvY/FqHh84QVB79w1TWnAr3vEo2t4QgKdGT6W8KEQnGULAzg46KzkzZoNG4iGjqwOHFBg@PN/u5A2tqKtGDqF@DqZ468Zjq6DkTHLcL73vQJPWrFhJ0YudyJnZUTpnGA3a9qQZpX3Q0TEn2YIw/h9MrSEx3SJ0LJ5rB1yWkPL1HIRMn9kLWGS@IYxO4EeJ3PXCK/p3en@JBq5w4tYhv4uQurtK1@XGDeXn3E/x14/vyA8PyWaHLm2/5oLCRTUPIh9p1DEcVn/shvG9Buq4BRVZE/MEn5b/C4F/2BeJhJgVPQynHb7GU3Elh0/hVzGEWtPfq7fZ2vf3sxZYVmQeqUuZGVeXeN91Ft3NydkXo8m/brJ1tHgUhYqLctrgyw55CA@4nQTuzGHLYDwYcf54NMaVmP@0/r@9sy2fa/NcDnJVqit87/A8)

Next answer must not exceed 982 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f6d  ODeerF$}++++[*/m
00000050: 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f 2b20 235c  ain(){//\. /+ #\
00000060: 0a20 5b20 2224 2862 6173 656e 616d 6520  . [ "$(basename 
00000070: 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20 2f70 726f  "$(readlink /pro
00000080: 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 2922 203d 2022  c/$$/exe)")" = "
00000090: 6261 7368 2220 5d20 2626 2065 6368 6f20  bash" ] && echo 
000000a0: 6873 6162 207c 7c20 6563 686f 2068 737a  hsab || echo hsz
000000b0: 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e0a 312b 2f2f  <<'EOF' #>>.1+//
000000c0: 2f5c 0a2f 2a1b 6767 6347 6d69 561b 5a5a  /\./*.ggcGmiV.ZZ
000000d0: 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d 3025 5321  ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!
000000e0: 3131 6f6f 6f3c 223e 3c3e 220a 2364 6566  11ooo<"><>".#def
000000f0: 696e 6520 5322 220a 2369 6664 6566 205f  ine S"".#ifdef _
00000100: 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  _OBJC__.#define 
00000110: 5322 2d65 7669 7463 656a 624f 220a 2365  S"-evitcejbO".#e
00000120: 6e64 6966 0a70 7269 6e74 6628 2243 2253  ndif.printf("C"S
00000130: 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274 2073 7464 2e73  )/*/import std.s
00000140: 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a  tdio;"D".write/*
00000150: 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 3c3c 0a20 2272 5422 3b23  */;}/*<<. "rT";#
00000160: 7a5f 2242 222c 403e 322b 3b20 203e 2020  z_"B",@>2+;  >  
00000170: 2020 5d5b 2076 3b23 3b38 6b2c 3779 322d    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-
00000180: 3b40 2c2c 203c 3c3c 0a3e 2242 6566 756e  ;@,, <<<.>"Befun
00000190: 6765 2d39 3622 235e 5a30 3047 235e 5f24  ge-96"#^Z00G#^_$
000001a0: 342d 3e31 2b3e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,
000001b0: 4028 0a6e 346a 5c59 7360 3929 7c62 4634  @(.n4j\Ys`9)|bF4
000001c0: 492a 6070 7c2a 2f2f 2f5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2  I*`p|*///]......
000001d0: 81b5 6c61 6f63 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b  ..laocrahC..++++
000001e0: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b  [-<+++++>]<[-<++
000001f0: 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  ++++<+++++<+++++
00000200: 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e  >>>]<<<+++++++.>
00000210: 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b  -.>---.<<-----.+
00000220: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d  +++++++.-----.>-
00000230: 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828  -.>---.<+.>>>(((
00000240: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d  (((((((()()()){}
00000250: 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928  ){}){}){}()){})(
00000260: 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29  (()()()()){}){})
00000270: 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d  [(([][]){}){}()]
00000280: 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928  )([]()){})[]())(
00000290: 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828  ([[][]()]([]()((
000002a0: 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29  ((([][][])){}{})
000002b0: 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20  []){})))[]())({ 
000002c0: 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 6d61 696e 3d70 7574  -}_=")";main=put
000002d0: 5374 7222 6c6c 656b 7361 4822 2d2d 202a  Str"lleksaH"-- *
000002e0: 2f2f 2f40 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  ///@,ka"89-egnuf
000002f0: 656e 5522                                enU"
```

### Explanation

Uses readlink and basename on `/proc/<shell pid>/exe` to distinguish the shell.

Answer (score 3):

## 21. emoji, 772 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*/main(){//\
 /+ #\
 [ "$(basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)")" = "bash" ] && echo hsab || echo hsz<<'EOF' #>>
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S""
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"-evitcejbO"
#endif
printf("C"S)/*/import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@(
n4j\Ys`9)|bF4I*`p|*///]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";main=putStr"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLcttIkmfhF@ZSBtUGIAIESdmyRJEc62lrx7YUlrvHY4pmg0CBhIUHAwAlyrImYn5gD3ucw2zsZU5znfNEzKf0F8wfeDLrAYIPd3fsLm2RVZXPyszKrAQ5dLLx168VcuB5xCF05ExHsfOK5AnMJkl4NwqTnOQ0y8nYSWOaZWR4R94E9Pgz/XSdDJUKOUrC0JlklKhHiUdV4sQeUQ/S0TSicZ6pJKNuHiRxRvwkJUOa5zQldDahaUBjlyqK6@SkS1ygVcKYWBkbsrfa0CcVckj9aTyi1t62kidTd0wmaQCMFRAd@OQumRIHdZcCTRI515Rk05TiLqLEC/w7AhrUJnckS0g@Bnn5mN4BCSVB7IZTj3owwEUSBvG1Qt1xQqyYqJsNFVTjtKXVJq56Sba4uo2rWRJF1PKDGcKUyV0@TuLtpdVXB29efH/w4mRw9ub45H2noRz@4d3JZUfd1G9dYrlt3LqhKrBrZjgSOvFo6oyobtwrG0yeWiGbi1xqZLNhkk3GCTwEDlOVjSH4FhgyjbvJNJ9Mc8FAbO5LSm@66As3p57kvbxuxaGyAZZ@RNxoQjgbIoHk8eP1AKDaR4vGygbn@/s0iUcCq0Ze0pk3jSYtgM5mHpHK@YGysWQeMIu@tNlqwwD7CHUtcvXjpo5BxJkYVz@iM5nrujJWHjBaxnk@yVq2PQry8XRYc5PIfpfeneXnMXid2nl6F@SJHFNqR04GsWrfps4EojUDDtITRMUToRKVqcDGyhx2DAAv8oiVTmMWx2XgJYYCIKRTOEd2MsltFhz8vZYOVwi67S6gy0hiFH6QjdkbhvQy/hFgMyzXyl3XHgaxDZ/rlTmCM@0mTliQiHkxWCfghyAC/JsgKs4qjGs5hEDX9uiNHU/DkDS7jxsYG@gXAS7zOB9@wqxwQy1Ud4T6zUhSLLqcr5WU15gIYFmzlxbLjItksSv3NCxWmC384TBY2dI8xSxRMRIYc32@kNwJQjxR1e29Mv0phMvx@SU5On9N/CCkJYfxNFFGfpGEa3w6SkLm1ix15Xid8b@Pyxuc3LEJsaws9zp7uzCYCoRv7/HZimWeWVHuBza@AQe5@G0OO7/AoVjeWeExTJ0g9qfudcFCLsxHK0Tv0l/YdJ5@Y9OMp@WHzqK8sQPyDnH00hHyiHWwQAipU@UfK0xfOtk1DUN2iIEVm6wgfWb0n9eQ0yj5FCy7ny3y97nbFZa9fKJdxe1JSrusMnS1oqxgasei6mLCSyY01jXE0IxaSh1PN1qMXnexTiapp7tGt7PdxPrMZ@1G8xnOXBJDkQ9ird19rNEQSrmvPa7cc6SHfc2ksdfRNMi5UqG2zVRp26jWVXwVX7A828Khxiq6SLyCQL2Ke5BrSQBZmmXYR/3eu7PzPuK/obMcLg3ZLdwLoilcNFAZOnMpVBfM/aymdRvb27/lw63Gtt2ot/ik@qRuGLzg1ZBZpSJLC85UBYsLqvolA25aZn@0CbxsrWRapkirqA5Y7cGvdqUyNzS/AXz9epMEHrG3rHvLIpXx20fvrefk4uP4j398//x5/ZjUj9XxDV/8MCbV90@J@vrRa0JDsP/r8yNyeX5MaXq6@VCFV28LCkwQQ1G37SuF2FVSgY8e1F8doo7GTkRxjJ7ESwkBUyeuvblp0xncDgyVdGSU9jErsko0zpwh@fJFTj6329rJ@alGKt2u0qjaKMje@s1o5L6Igh9@8@HDfpIkapi8UPd/26l/d/mo0YCFNis5SsWjPjiKXKowDnyYkcHg/PA/jgaDEsyiN0Hu0k/Dc8CCMAl8YVkdCtGlYW/ZQTRJ0pzAWa3BX5DsQ32s3aZBTu2tLXv/wd5qtxU4Su/U/crngXqoms@7zeo@gcsUvPo9crNf2d@9Np/dNa3956ZJ2oDfLSejyscP9fqLysfB5hOr26h2zeL1XFfiJ5@u/pD9uGd8GZ4@Odv6cfJlC@zQ/@k///zPf/z0p7@HTuKmzvjon39lPrHa@FHt9ttyWG2X3rtdgLQFoFrrWvDfsmrttoWvWlUC@LRrSTigdrv6/GXgP@P@ofjPZxJSwHq63uv3@hKnb8CUA9knQBEMALbOWOMCUAAOw0JcQ2DfE@th0IHQ2cfA68Bd6TJP1TCk15nzUoWQRsv867//62/BpySiOPjpL//z3Lx21N09i47iqU/j79WvfppE5HMYDAl37ZYiXIxhu/NE8TuhEw09h8QtlpNiU0uHRU5SvM5Qw7i9mvk@/mlVX9dq7LoPx0wzqkNtDuJjrfYpgZPi66cGprtTSFU9nulMjR9NGPBCC4PyZVvrG4rbgZse5Kksg3uDvmcen5y@Onh3cmxarw/eD35/ePbuEtcGr09eD16d/HDyyqwbPIh1vqPacOcJtCogT3drkpfuGVW35ofTbKwb5lB7bsMWPcqwYK9ZngYTXetohgHNFdwNrDCArmS2u0OiIA4iJyQ0moZOjj3RUkMF2QJbkaL7uk3S64yMaUpNTKC3AZQbXMOsD0YNkb0J1k9B5xEZTkcZZwK4XkKzWOMsBAdsmCCVDJ1heEdiTLLQJUEKhsMLFPOmioHGNJyAwHwsMFBAPg4y4gxhhw7rT0wCJZBEVLZQLtofcj9JoOpAkoCP6E4keFiMOQO4YULkwQlWZPhkd5nCYos1PkkSZiLAyMRJ88AJFYVpUip0PLJAPvGhk4BdjVIngsToy2CLoKJC2emQ3htQpb@18/Tp9o5Y7TWf7rTgrwpq6ILW6AOuGCseDYuxktJRgO1ABgj32tmF1iL1WaNeN4l2eVaaHL1nk3r99NRUNrRjnKJsxLuYj4/P5BiQDiQN43BYIjmUJA8KXGJGXPjRKSyeOlCnAeO8PPlQnlyWJxfFBFohzOU0TZNUj7KRwSyH0e6rJ2/fnr9tkXtYfoCPYs@P0gfVUDbAQzU6C3K9YXAmI5oP0BEDLMA6csIBKCksXDDoocX6fdZHMhSIANxWS@ihQVFzpzmG1zTmxcUTTDQQvMSHVDukgav5NI0ZvyV1bvHqguqECSizpKWyMQ7WrQp2OkDbbbJrkCoJE0V5e/LiEgMIvcT9i@5j74fsHdzKPcVDgTu3j3QvD16dIu299LHOmTA/GCapkINXADrioKNF0NErGT46FzcHHSPokIMOF0GHCGKBJmS9S6dC1EskupiLKiBHCGFBLCQVkGOEHJ/NBRWQw5eKCCRIhkl4QwdR4qXRLrN6GpmwPIKdLwAbO2hmTExZEGe5E7tUR1TIJEgFZEAhzdZLoz5z/MIaHfULRwkpa7RAQcCQjdd5@vDg8gRd2pMeBH@ZRM6O5exiAXZRhsnVEq7kgFEOaXAgY5brf9nj2tg22SXfkd0@U48dFbkOpZObgK8AEjMWR@uQbWYivnXGEAxkkrIkZQPv7oiGdQsY1WGIBROtCMkZt41UiIGc56cK7bpyJKdxRvMCCRkEUABS6LzFySSO60IlxAMqRFY7S0ylLo9BGSjkvq8oG@VN1QtdIpzusKnc5dJxXt7sRrHdggJl8aBAYElOg6HJE851XY4LgzwWSq5IKgQ5WUahIEm2zZ/jyrX@JleZsXbhij8aJOkAjIpRu3Q@ChiQTych5SeFjkwyDkZjdsQkBgA8J3d4xMMZAIjBzY2oZQswNAg5VrTK@yvDv5NgCRXM57ldyO1zIQwsg4i5h8WRr2It5pkdA0rGTg7s7@dMWvXmjBWZsg7cSNmikUwG@j@bKgm9n7NUJgEm0dnOZE1AOmEao2y6EgHD55jc@QxVYq7aD/QA2wQjKHq7TNi8vHKWvyo8ZBoVblo4iP8rTxVHv@SmVRcV@2K1dm1wsHq7AgELNYRCQCrUIZCuAP3/L4yWy7kIqAW7/pqIKorUOrOWHAiMuQcX7bIMnp8ubp0VeOl0rg0Y2MsaCLMpQMeB2KkIKsle7FFOoceuz575rfmC1ZFihf0kpMwPlPx5hv46lt9kOo/9OU@BKFhIYy2ggxa/gC8p0KHp4JPrDrIx9BO6m0Ahw9aFU4br7gisPoaFgXA8t02AD4QFjxZZczsF9LLoAFq9xs5gO5mwi0mWug2IuSxff0NCMECKXfI0gKsGhzaXoAv1BneUTUPkzRht4UezfIcGwUsRyymAlDUZPeww@mUZi7QGecT0BpKC4gOnKNGX9z9LUn4zBHIT9Vne@C7bN@Z5hjESI4N85GMgMURSnEDHLU9Ja6E1uLxgOnBz4cwgFpbo4riXEc3lEyfZJxNxfVyopSWmoOlqe4MsUThmrW/B5eHkOKuKr6I3ldVqKCIK@jV29mIgSKeT/BsxXIJj9DbZhavo43hZWoPG7kvYh3O2u3q5mzBEN4H8OQ7S1PdYthZfA3aIprELk@elc59Ad8Eui7fjIKSMGb@@xfQWkNxxqjNhSGQwRE7P2z1@UWSowH0TmpIhlIRrBhBSARHguMI7Wr4sH1@Xq7UoKtr3cRDBVQEfWLAvgfNmgxRfvEJlwTGrKVopo3@TWNgQ6IpJQawwx03Fd@GsKQRDey3Cn5a1RFXidh4VY4zh5SNuIul2vVU6XXzp6S9z@7iOWwVUflIHSfXZ01P8Oh22M6Rhcotcd3bnXMXhW6vQzl5rJd0xwLOdOYPlVFxOOFD6S9mEM3W91jziseWUE5e3huJRI0xapHQDm1/r8NAZgsqjv5rKmlPhnlfJ5pYQJAV6MvlZISLBGAp2ZtBR0ZkpGzQaTyOaOnB4scHD481@MsGamlL0IOrnYKKnTjyiOnrOBMftwPsuNEm9soUEndi5nIkdFVOmcZ9db8pB2hMdDVOSPRjjz@H0EhLTHVLnwolm8HUJKU/vUMjYib2QdcYL4tgEboT43Q@cot/RuxM8aKUTp07j6zi5jct0LX7cYF7c/QR/3fi6/MCweFbo8uZbPiisZZMQ8qF2FcNRxed@CO9ZkK4rQJFNI/7gk/JfcvAvDAPxMJOCp6GU47daSu6ksGn8auYgC1q71VarWW09ebZlRea@qhS5UVW590130e2cnF0ROvzbN2u7yaMgREyU2xJXZthTaMD9JGhlFkMOe0Gf48@zIabU7Lu9p9XtpnymzX@BwFmppvjNxL8B)

Next answer must not exceed 1003 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f6d  ODeerF$}++++[*/m
00000050: 6169 6e28 297b 2f2f 5c0a 202f 2b20 235c  ain(){//\. /+ #\
00000060: 0a20 5b20 2224 2862 6173 656e 616d 6520  . [ "$(basename 
00000070: 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20 2f70 726f  "$(readlink /pro
00000080: 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 2922 203d 2022  c/$$/exe)")" = "
00000090: 6261 7368 2220 5d20 2626 2065 6368 6f20  bash" ] && echo 
000000a0: 6873 6162 207c 7c20 6563 686f 2068 737a  hsab || echo hsz
000000b0: 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e0a 312b 2f2f  <<'EOF' #>>.1+//
000000c0: 2f5c 0a2f 2a1b 6767 6347 6d69 561b 5a5a  /\./*.ggcGmiV.ZZ
000000d0: 3b6f 6f6f 226c 6f47 223b 3f3d 3025 5321  ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!
000000e0: 3131 6f6f 6f3c 223e 3c3e 220a 2364 6566  11ooo<"><>".#def
000000f0: 696e 6520 5322 220a 2369 6664 6566 205f  ine S"".#ifdef _
00000100: 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  _OBJC__.#define 
00000110: 5322 2d65 7669 7463 656a 624f 220a 2365  S"-evitcejbO".#e
00000120: 6e64 6966 0a70 7269 6e74 6628 2243 2253  ndif.printf("C"S
00000130: 292f 2a2f 696d 706f 7274 2073 7464 2e73  )/*/import std.s
00000140: 7464 696f 3b22 4422 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a  tdio;"D".write/*
00000150: 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 3c3c 0a20 2272 5422 3b23  */;}/*<<. "rT";#
00000160: 7a5f 2242 222c 403e 322b 3b20 203e 2020  z_"B",@>2+;  >  
00000170: 2020 5d5b 2076 3b23 3b38 6b2c 3779 322d    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-
00000180: 3b40 2c2c 203c 3c3c 0a3e 2242 6566 756e  ;@,, <<<.>"Befun
00000190: 6765 2d39 3622 235e 5a30 3047 235e 5f24  ge-96"#^Z00G#^_$
000001a0: 342d 3e31 2b3e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,
000001b0: 4028 0a6e 346a 5c59 7360 3929 7c62 4634  @(.n4j\Ys`9)|bF4
000001c0: 492a 6070 7c2a 2f2f 2f5d e28e 9ac2 bfe2  I*`p|*///]......
000001d0: 81b5 6c61 6f63 7261 6843 c2a6 2b2b 2b2b  ..laocrahC..++++
000001e0: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b  [-<+++++>]<[-<++
000001f0: 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  ++++<+++++<+++++
00000200: 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e  >>>]<<<+++++++.>
00000210: 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b  -.>---.<<-----.+
00000220: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d  +++++++.-----.>-
00000230: 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828  -.>---.<+.>>>(((
00000240: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d  (((((((()()()){}
00000250: 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928  ){}){}){}()){})(
00000260: 2828 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29  (()()()()){}){})
00000270: 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d  [(([][]){}){}()]
00000280: 2928 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928  )([]()){})[]())(
00000290: 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828  ([[][]()]([]()((
000002a0: 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29  ((([][][])){}{})
000002b0: 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20  []){})))[]())({ 
000002c0: 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b 6d61 696e 3d70 7574  -}_=")";main=put
000002d0: 5374 7222 6c6c 656b 7361 4822 2d2d 202a  Str"lleksaH"-- *
000002e0: 2f2f 2ff0 9f92 ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac  ///....ijome....
000002f0: e29e a140 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  ...@,ka"89-egnuf
00000300: 656e 5522                                enU"
```

## How?

Emoji ignores everything except for the `ijome➡` which prints `ijome`.

Answer (score 3):

## 23. C++, 893 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 [ "$(basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)")" = "bash" ] && echo hsab || echo hsz<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
 f();
#include<cstdio>
#define S"++C"
 int
#endif
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@<
Sjqo>@5y,b%Ja [Zao*///]]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLctvKlWvhF7JpgbIBiABBUrYsUySjt@3EtlSW743HFM2AQIOEhQcDgBJlWanKD2Qxy1kkNZtZzXbWU5VPuV8wf@A5px8g@PC9t2ZCW2R3n1f3efYBOXSy8bdvFXLoecQhdORMR7HzmuQJzCZJeDcKk5zkNMvJ2EljmmVkeEfeBvTkC/18nQyVCjlOwtCZZJSox4lHVeLEHlEP09E0onGeqSSjbh4kcUb8JCVDmuc0JXQ2oWlAY5cqiuvkpEtcoFXCmFgZG7K32tAnFXJE/Wk8otbzHSVPpu6YTNIAGCsgOvDJXTIlDu5dCjRJ5FxTkk1TiqeIEi/w7wjsoDa5I1lC8jHIy8f0DkgoCWI3nHrUgwEukjCIrxXqjhNixUTdaqiwNU5bWm3iqpdki6s7uJolUUQtP5ghTJnc5eMk3llafX349sUPhy9OB6/enpx@6DSUo395f3rZUbf0W5dYbhuPbqgKnJopjoROPJo6I6ob98oGk6dWyNYilxrZaphki3ECC4HBVIn7bhrHQTwi7DCPm8rGEEwOcthBusk0n0xzgSvO/DWlN100kZtTT7JZXrfiUNkAA2wSN5oQzoZIIHn8eD0AqPZR0bGywfn@IU1gbxyrRl7SmTeNJi2AzmYekZvzA2VjSWugLX1JB9WGYRSntsjVH7d09C3OxLj6I9qYKaErXegBnWic55OsZdujIB9PhzU3iez36d2r/DwGZ6B2nt4FeSLHlNqRk4EL27epMwEnzoCDNBBRMVBUorItsLEyh50AwIs8YqXTmLl3GXiJHgII6RTCy04muc18hr/X0uEKQbfdBXTpYIzCD7Ixe0NPX8Y/BmyG5Vq569rDILbhc/1mjiHU3cQJCxIxLwbrBPwYRIB/E0RFCMO4loMLdG2P3tjxNAxJs/u4gb6BdhHgMo/z4WdMFjfUwu2OcH8zkhSLLudrJeU1JgJY1uylxTLjIofsyTMNixWmC384DFaONM88S1SMBMZ8P19J7gQhRlR153mZ/gzc5eT8khyfvyF@ENKSwXj2KCO/SMI1Nh0lITNrlrpyvE75P8TlA07u2IRYVpZ7ned7MJgKhO@f8dmKZp5ZUe4HNr4BB7n4fQ67v8ChWN5d4TFMnSD2p@51wUIuzEcrRO/TXzh0nn7n0Iyn5YfOoryxA/KOcPTSEfKIdbhACKlT5R8rTF862TUNQxbEwIpNVpC@MPova8hplHwOls3PFvn7OrMLkdUjWLlwsLLG2aJ860MZthrp1SoGWrWKgebChwwwdzKZB5aYqFDQMG/6RLuK25OUdlmp6mpFncOiglXexVSbTGisa4ihGbWUOp5utBi97mLhTlJPd41uZ6eJFwY@azeaz3DmkhhuHUGstbuPNRrC3cLXHlfuOdLDvmbS2OtoGmR7uaG2zbbStnFbV/FVfMEyfAuHGrtiiJQvCNSruAdZngRQH1hu3@z33r867yP@WzrL4RaT3cJFJZrCzQc3Q2cuhbqGVYcV2W5jZ@e3fLjd2LEb9RafVJ/UDYNX4Boyq1RkUcOZqmBZw61@zYCbltmfbAIvWyuplm2kVdQlvH6ARe1KZa5ofiX59u0mCTxib1v3lkUq43ebH6wDcvFp/Oc/fzg4qJ@Q@ok6vuGLH8ek@uEpUd9sviE0BP2/OT8ml@cnlKZnWw9VePW2bdu@UohdJRX46EHJ18HRaexEFMdoQrweEdBx4tpbWzadwT3FUElHBkYf/YUVv3HmDMnXr3Lypd3WTs/PNFLpdq@URpVJsrd/Mxq5L6Lgx998/LifJIkaJi/U/d926o8uNxsNWGizMqdUPOqDicglVDGlEvgwJYOBOwmnGf4pxNeNfQDwu1zbhQQQJN0SWbUKhOBPuVIBzwn8OZPzo98dDwZlCRa9CXKXfh6eqxIbbpRBDLcvbiL90rC3bbEURJMkzQlIrDGp@1Dma7dpkFN7e9vef7C3H9ptBULyvbpf@TJQj1TzoNus7hO4K8Kr3yM3@5X9vWvz2V3T2j8wTdIG/G45qVY@fazXX1Q@DbaeWN1GtWsWr4O2cvn5T0n34OmdOXz0O4f0PjoJWrHf/@mv//aP//7pL/8VOombOuPjf/wHM7HVxo9qt9@Ww2q79N7tAqQtANVa14L/llVrty181aoSwKddS8IBtdvV5y8D/xn3D8V/PpOQAtbT9V6/15c4fQOmHMg@AYpgALB1xhoXgAJwGBbiGgL7nlgPgw445L6@aXQy@qd9NNLXkOZkuAkAtQP3wMs83dJVdVPN4hR6EecC2p2jqmpAIgxDep05L1WIJVTi//z9X/8z@JxEFAc//e3fD8xrR917btFRPPVp/IP6zU@TiHwJgyHhbrCtCHfAsNl9ovid0ImGnkPiFkuGsamlwyIZKl5nqGHcXM18H/@0qq9rNdb4QHxrRnWozUF8rNU@J@B3vn5mYJ49A5/u8RRrajwnwIDfLWBQbju0vqG4HbjcQoLMMrgq6c/Nk9Oz14fvT09M683hh8Efjl69v8S1wZvTN4PXpz@evjbrBs9LOj9Rbbj7BJo2kKe7NclL94yqW/MhEMe6YQ61AxuO6FGGBWfN8jSY6FpHMwxoM@E6ZIUB9GezvV0SBXEQOSGh0TR0cuwOl1pLSFPYlBV96G2SXmdkTFNqYua@DaDC4RqWG1BqiOxN0H6aYsMznI4yzgRwvYRmscZZCA7YOkIqGzrD8I7EmN2hX4TcD0EPFPP2koHGNJyAwHwsMFBAPg4y4gzhhA7r1EwCVZdEVDaTLuofig5JoNxBdoGP6E5UFliMOQO4VIPnQbAr0n2yu0xhvsVawCQJM@FgZOKkeeCEisJ2Uqqw3LNAPvGheYJTjVIngsTsS2eL4BIB9a5Dem9hK/3t3adPd3bFaq/5dLcFf1XYhi5ojT7girHi0bAYKykdBdgBZYBwr7260FqkPmvU6ybRLl@VJscf2KRePzszlQ3tBKcoG/Eu5uOTV3IMSIeShnE4KpEcSZIHBe5tIy78@AwWzxy4IADGeXnysTy5LE8uigl0f1gEaJomqR5lI4NpDr3dV0/fvTt/1yL3sPwAH8WZN9MH1VA2wEI1OgtyvWFwJiOaD9AQA6z8OnLCAWxSaLhg0EON9fusdWYo4AF4rJbYhwZF1Z3m6F7TmFclTzDRQPASH1LtkAau5tM0ZvyWtnOLdybcTpjAZpZ2qWyMg3Wrgp0O0Hab7BmkSsJEUd6dvrhEB0Ircfui@dj7EXsHs3JLcVfgxu0j3cvD12dIey9trHMmzA6GSSrk8DWAjjnoeBF0/Fq6j87FzUEnCDrioKNF0BGCmKMJWe/TqRD1Eoku5qIKyDFCmBMLSQXkBCEnr@aCCsjRS0U4EiTDJLyhgyjx0miPaT2NTFgewckXgI1dVDMmpiyIs9yJXaojKmQSpAIyoJBq66VRnxl@YY2O@oWhhJQ1u0BBwJCN11n66PDyFE3akxYEe5lEzk7k7GIBdlGGydUSruSAXg5pcCB9lu//ssd3Y9tkjzwie322PRYqch1KJ1cBXwEkpiyO1iE7TEX86IwhKMgkZUnKBjYNiIZ1CxjVYYgFE7UIyRmPjVSIgZznUYV6XQnJaZzBHaI4BjAIoACk1M1FZBLHdaESYoAKkdXOElO5l8ewGSjkvq8oG@VD1Yu9RDjdZVN5yqVwXj7sRnHcggJlcadAYElOg6HJCOd7XfYLgzwWm1yRVAhysoxCQZJsmz/Hle/6u1xlxtqDFmM0SNIBKBW9dik@ChiQTych5ZFCRyYZB6MxCzGJAQDPyR3u8RADADG4uhG1rAGGBi7Hilb5fGX4IwmWUMF8ntuF3D4XwsDSiZh5mB/5KtZintnRoaTv5MD@fs6kVW/OWJEp74ErKVtUkslA/29VJaH3c5rKJMAkOjuZrAlIJ1RjlFVXImD4HJMbn6FKzFX9wT5AN8EIit4eEzYvr5zlr3IPmUaFmRYC8f9kqSL0S2ZaNVFxLlZr1zoHq7crENBQQ2wISMV2CKQrQP/nudFyORcOtaDXX@NRRZFap9aSAYExt@CiXpbB8@ji2lmBl6JzrcPAWdZAmE4BOg7ESYVTSfbijHIK7Xh99sxvzResjhQr9CchZX6wyZ9n6K9j@V2mc9@f8xSIgoVU1gI67OIX8CUFGjQdfHbdQTaGfkJ3Eyhk2LpwynDdHYHVx7BQEI7nugnwGbjg0SJrbqeAXhYdQKvX2B3sJBN2MclStwE@l@Xrb0gIBkhxSp4GcNXg0OYSdKHe4ImyaYi8GaNt/GiW79AgeMljOQWQsiajhx1GvyxjkdYgm2zfQFJQfOQUJfry@WdJym@GQG7ifpYPvsfOjXmeYYzEyCCf@BhIDJEUJ9BxyyhpLbQGlxdsD1xdODOIhSW6CPcyorkccZJ9MhHXx4VaWmIKO11tb5AlCses9T24DE6Os7rxVfSmsloNhUdBv8ZiLwaCdDrJv@PDJTh6b5NduIo@jpelNWjsvoR9OGe7p5e7CUN0E8if4yBN/TnL1uKbzw7RNHZh8rx0bhPoLthl8XYchJQx49e3mN4CkjtOdSYMiQyGyOl5u8cvigwVuG9BUzKEknDNAEIqIAIcV3hHy5flc/NytRZFRfshDiK4KuADC/Z1eN5skOIraKgsOGY1RStl9O8SCx0CXTEpiBVmuKn4VQBrCkHRXovwp2UtUZW4nkfFGH14OcRNJN2pt0rRxZee/jK3T@u4VWDLT@ogqT57eoY/LIDjDGmY3CLX3b05VxF8aze0@7y1ku4Y4NnunMFyKi4nHCj9pWzCmbpea@7x2HLKictbQ/GoESYtUrqBza91GHSGoPLor6ay5lR45lWyuSYESYGeTH5WiEgwhoKdGXRUdGbKBo3G04imDgQvNngY3uzHI6ypKXkPon4JJnrqxCOqo@VMMNwuvO9Bk9Qra0jQiZPLmThRMWU77rPrTdlJe6KjYZtkD8b4czi9hMT2DqlzIaIZfF1CytM7FDJ2Yi9knfGCODaBGyF@6QRR9Ht6d4qBVoo4dRpfx8ltXKZr8XCDeXH3E/x149vyA8PiWaHLm2/5oLCWTULIh9pVDKGKz/0Q3rMgXVeAIptG/MEn5b9p4d8XBuJhJgVLQynHr9OU3Enh0PjV0GEWtPaqrVaz2nrybNuKzH1VKXKjqnLrm@6i2Tk5uyJ0@Nd@1k6Te0GImCi3Ja7McKbQgPtJ0Moshhz2gj7Hn2dDTKnZo@dPqztN@Uyb/@iCs1JN8TOR/wU)

Next answer must not exceed 1160 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 205b 2022 2428  /\. /+ #\. [ "$(
00000060: 6261 7365 6e61 6d65 2022 2428 7265 6164  basename "$(read
00000070: 6c69 6e6b 202f 7072 6f63 2f24 242f 6578  link /proc/$$/ex
00000080: 6529 2229 2220 3d20 2262 6173 6822 205d  e)")" = "bash" ]
00000090: 2026 2620 6563 686f 2068 7361 6220 7c7c   && echo hsab ||
000000a0: 2065 6368 6f20 6873 7a3c 3c27 454f 4627   echo hsz<<'EOF'
000000b0: 2023 3e3e 5c0a 312b 2f2f 2f5c 0a2f 2a1b   #>>\.1+///\./*.
000000c0: 6767 6347 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c  ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"l
000000d0: 6f47 223b 3f3d 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f3c  oG";?=0%S!11ooo<
000000e0: 223e 3c3e 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322  "><>".#define S"
000000f0: 4322 0a23 6966 6465 6620 5f5f 6370 6c75  C".#ifdef __cplu
00000100: 7370 6c75 730a 2066 2829 3b0a 2369 6e63  splus. f();.#inc
00000110: 6c75 6465 3c63 7374 6469 6f3e 0a23 6465  lude<cstdio>.#de
00000120: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 220a 2069 6e74  fine S"++C". int
00000130: 0a23 656e 6469 660a 2369 6664 6566 205f  .#endif.#ifdef _
00000140: 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  _OBJC__.#define 
00000150: 5322 432d 6576 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23  S"C-evitcejbO".#
00000160: 656e 6469 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072  endif. main(){pr
00000170: 696e 7466 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829  intf(S)/*/main()
00000180: 7b69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469  {import std.stdi
00000190: 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b  o;"D".write/**/;
000001a0: 7d2f 2a7d 3c3c 0a20 2272 5422 3b23 7a5f  }/*}<<. "rT";#z_
000001b0: 2242 222c 403e 322b 3b20 203e 2020 2020  "B",@>2+;  >    
000001c0: 5d5b 2076 3b23 3b38 6b2c 3779 322d 3b40  ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@
000001d0: 2c2c 203c 3c3c 0a3e 2242 6566 756e 6765  ,, <<<.>"Befunge
000001e0: 2d39 3622 235e 5a30 3047 235e 5f24 342d  -96"#^Z00G#^_$4-
000001f0: 3e31 2b3e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c  >1+>,,,,,,,,,,@<
00000200: 0a53 6a71 6f3e 4035 792c 6225 4a61 205b  .Sjqo>@5y,b%Ja [
00000210: 5a61 6f2a 2f2f 2f5d 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281  Zao*///]].......
00000220: b56c 616f 6372 6168 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b  .laocrahC..++++[
00000230: 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b  -<+++++>]<[-<+++
00000240: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e  +++<+++++<+++++>
00000250: 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d  >>]<<<+++++++.>-
00000260: 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b  .>---.<<-----.++
00000270: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d  ++++++.-----.>--
00000280: 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828  .>---.<+.>>>((((
00000290: 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29  ((((((()()()){})
000002a0: 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828  {}){}){}()){})((
000002b0: 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b  ()()()()){}){})[
000002c0: 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29  (([][]){}){}()])
000002d0: 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828  ([]()){})[]())((
000002e0: 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828  [[][]()]([]()(((
000002f0: 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b  (([][][])){}{})[
00000300: 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28 2929 287b 202d  ]){})))[]())({ -
00000310: 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d  }_=")";(!)=seq;m
00000320: 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70  ain|let b!_=""=p
00000330: 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574  utStr$(""!"snret
00000340: 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229 2b2b 226c 6c65  taPgnaB+")++"lle
00000350: 6b73 6148 222d 2d20 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac  ksaH"-- *///....
00000360: 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 402c 6b61  ijome.......@,ka
00000370: 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665 6e55 22         "89-egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 3):

## 24. Emotinomicon, 922 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 [ "$(basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)")" = "bash" ] && echo hsab || echo hsz<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
 f();
#include<cstdio>
#define S"++C"
 int
#endif
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,, <<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@<
Sjqo>@5y,b%Ja [Zao*///]]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrLctvKlWvhF7JpgbIBiABBUrYsUySjt@3EtlSW7o3HFM2AQIOEhAeDh0RZVqryA7lVs5rKIqnZTNVMZTZTNeupyqf4C/IHnnO60SD48L23ZkJbZHefZ58@fR4gh1Yy/vq1QvYdh1iEjqxsFFqvSRrBbBL5dyM/SklKk5SMrTikSUKGd@StR48@0avraChVyGHk@9YkoUQ@jBwqEyt0iLwfj7KAhmkik4TaqReFCXGjmAxpmtKY0OmExh4NbSpJtpWSLrGBVvJDYiRsyN5qQ5dUyAF1s3BEjedbUhpl9phMYg8YSyDac8ldlBELdRcCdRJY15QkWUxxF0HkeO4dAQ1qkzuSRCQdg7x0TO@AhBIvtP3MoQ4McJH4XngtUXscESMk8kZDBtU4bWm1iatOlMyvbuFqEgUBNVxvijBpcpeOo3BrYfX1/tsX3@2/OB68ent0/L7TkA7@6eL4vCNvqLc2Mew2bl2TJdg1MxzxrXCUWSOqavfSGpMnV8jGPJca2WjoZINxghOCA5MF7rssDL1wRNhmHjeltSEcOchhG@lGWTrJ0hw33/PnmN508YjslDqCzeK6EfrSGhzAOrGDCeFsiACSx49XA4BqFw0dSmuc72/iCHTjWDXykk6dLJi0ADqdOkQo53rS2oLVwFrqgg2qDU0rdm2Qy99uqOhbnIl2@Vs8Y2aErnChB3SicZpOkpZpjrx0nA1rdhSYF/Hdq/Q0BGegZhrfeWkkxpSagZWAC5u3sTUBJ06AgzggIuNFkYnMVGBjaQY7AoATOMSIs5C5dxl4jh4CCHEG18uMJqnJfIa/1@LhEkG33QV04WCMwvWSMXtDT1/EPwRshmUbqW2bQy804XO1Modw1e3I8guSfF4MVgn43gsA/8YLiisM41oKLtA1HXpjhpnvk2b3cQN9A88lB5d5nA6vMFjcUAPVHaF@UxIVizbna0TlNSYCWNbMhcUy4yKG7Ig9DYsVZgt3OPSWtjSLPAtUjATGXJ/PJLU8H29Udet5mf4E3OXo9Jwcnr4hrufT0oHx6FFGfhH5K850FPnsWJPYFuNVxv8uLG9wcscmxDCS1Ok834FBliN8e4/PlizzzAhS1zPxDTiIxW9z2P4JDsXy9hKPYWx5oZvZ1wULsTAbLRFdxD@x6TT@xqYZT8P1rXl5YwvkHeDopZXLI8b@HCGETpl/LDF9aSXX1PfZJQZWbLKE9InRf1pBToPoyls8frbI31cdey6yegArZxZm1jCZl2@8L8OWb3q1ihetWsWLZsOHuGD2ZDK7WPmkTHgcRKkXRoFnRyEGvOkkilPy9vToeHC2f/GycymbWRKbvjc0Q2A5gDSc@TS5lJEjrhT7K9jMTWpXQlmJxWqXKJdhexLTLkuPXaXIrZjIsLKwMbxHExqqCmIoWi2mlqNqLUav2lgsRLGj2lq3s9XEIoXP2o3mM5zZoFYKPJR297FCfahnXOVx5Z4jPewqOg2djqJAhhEKtU2mSttEtS7Dy/CMZZUWDhVW1uRpJieQL8MeZBbiQU5i@WS937t4ddpH/Ld0mkLllNxCcRRkUG2hMnRqU8ilmOlYYu82trZ@yYebjS2zUW/xSfVJXdN41q8hs0pFJFKcyRKmUlT1cwLclMT8aBJ4mUrJtEyRVpELseQBLzIrlZmheRn09etN5DnE3DTuDYNUxu/W3xt75Ozj@Pe/f7@3Vz8i9SN5fMMXP4xJ9f1TIr9Zf0OoD/Z/c3pIzk@PKI1PNh6q8OptmqZ5KRGzSirw0YMyQ4XLRUMroDjGI8SSjICNI9vc2DDpFGojTSYdcRn76FEs4Y4Ta0g@fxaTT@22cnx6opBKt3spNapMkrn5i9HIfhF43//iw4fdKIpkP3oh7/6yU390vt5owEKbpVap4lAXjoicQ@aUKp4LUzIY2BM/S/BPIq6q7QKA149tG4KOF3VLZNUqEII/pVIFPMdzZ0xOD351OBiUJRj0xkttejU8lQU2VLFeCBUfPyL1XDM3zXzJC9hlA4k1JnUXSovabeyl1NzcNHcfzM2HdluCMHAh71Y@DeQDWd/rNqu7BOpTePV75Ga3srtzrT@7axq7e7pO2oDfLQfyyscP9fqLysfBxhOj26h29eK115bOr34Xdfee3unDR7@ySO@DFeEp9vtf/vinv/3Plz/8t29FdmyND//2b@yIjTZ@VLv9thhW26X3bhcg7RxQrXUN@G8YtXbbwFetKgB82jUEHFC7XXX20vCfdv9Q/OczASlgPVXt9Xt9gdPXYMqB7BOgCAYAW2escQEoAIdhIa6WY98T42HQAYfcVde1TkJ/t4uH9NmnKRmuA0DuQO15nsYbqiyvy0kYQ/9jnUGLdVCVNQi@vk@vE@ulDHcJjfj3v/zzX72rKKA4@PLnf/37X/7lP8uhFub/9eWH//jyw1@//PDve/q1Je88N@gozFwafid/deMoIJ8g6BLuI5tS7it4p7afSG7Ht4KhY5GwxSJlqCvxsIiUktMZKnipLqeui39K1VWVGuvE4PIrWnWozEB8rNSuInBKVz3RMAifgMP3ePzVFR4wYMCLHRiU@yClr0l2B6ptiJ5JArWb@lw/Oj55vX9xfKQbb/bfD35z8OriHNcGb47fDF4ff3/8Wq9rPGipfEe14fYT6CJBnmrXBC/V0ap2zYVbOlY1fajsmbBFhzIs2GuSxt5EVTqKpkHfC/WZ4XvQME53tknghV5g@YQGmW@l2K4u9LoQw7BLLBrj2yi@TsiYxlTHsH7rQcrFNcxFYFQf2etg/TjGDmyYjRLOBHCdiCahwlnkHLCXhTg3tIb@HQkx9EMDC4kBIgJQzPpdBhpTfwIC03GOgQLSsZcQawg7tFjrqBMoA0hARXdro/0hI5EIciGEHvgI7vK0A4shZwBVPrglRAJJuE9yl0jMt1hPGkV@kjsYmVhx6lm@JDFNSumXexbIJy50c7CrUWwFELVd4WwBpHtIhh3Sewuq9De3nz7d2s5Xe82n2y34q4Iaak6r9QE3H0sO9YuxFNORhy1ZAgj3yqszpUXq00a9rhPl/FVpcvieTer1kxNdWlOOcIqyEe9sNj56JcaAtC9oGIeDEsmBIHmQoJAcceGHJ7B4YkH1ABin5cmH8uS8PDkrJtCOYoagcRzFapCMNGY59HZXPn737vRdi9zD8gN8FHtejx9kTVqDE6rRqZeqDY0zGdF0gAcxwLJARU44ACVzCxcMemixfp/18gwFPAC31cr1UCDj2lmK7pWFPGU5ORMFBC/wIdUOaeBqmsUh47egzi0WVKiOH4EyC1pKa2Nv1WrOTgVou012NFIlfiRJ745fnKMD4Snx88XjY@8H7B2OlZ8UdwV@uH2ke7n/@gRp78UZq5wJOwdNJxWy/xpAhxx0OA86fC3cR@XiZqAjBB1w0ME86ABBzNFyWRdxlot6iURnM1EF5BAhzIlzSQXkCCFHr2aCCsjBSyl3JAiGkX/Diu842GFWjwMdlkew8zlgYxvNjIEp8cIktUKbqogKkQSpgAwohNl6cdBnBz@3Rkf94qByKSu0QEHAkI1XnfTB/vkxHmlPnCCcl07E7EjMzuZgZ2WYWC3hCg7o5RAGB8Jnuf7nPa6NaZId8ojs9Jl67KqIdUid3AR8BZCYsThah2wxE/GtM4ZgIJ2UJUlr2FEgGuYtYFSHISZMtCIEZ9w2UiEGcp7dKrTr0pXMwgQKjGIbwMCDBBBTO81vJrFsGzIhXtBcZLWzwFTo8hiUgUTuupK0Vt5UvdAlwOk2m4pdLlznxc2uFdstKFAWdwoEluQ0GJq44VzXRb/QyONcySVJhSArSSgkJMG2@WNcudbf5Coi1g70H6NBFA/AqOi1C/ejgAF5NvEpvyl0pJOxNxqzKyYwAOBYqcU9Hu4AQDRubkQtW4ChgcuxpFXeXxn@SIAFNGc@i@253D4XwsDCidjxMD9yZczFPLKjQwnfSYH9/YxJq96csiRT1oEbKZk3ks5A/29TRb7zY5ZKBEAnKtuZyAlIl5tGK5uuRMDwOSY/fIYqMJftB3qAbbwRJL0dJmyWXjnLn@UeIozmxzR3Ef9PJ1Vc/dIxLR9RsS@Wa1c6B8u3SxCwUCNXCEhzdQiEK0D/x7nRYjrPHWrOrj/Ho4oktcqspQMExvwE5@2yCJ7dLm6dJXjpdq50GNjLCgizKUDHXr7T3KkE@3yPYgq9en36zG3NFoyOEJvbT0DK/EDJH2formL5TaYz35/xzBFzFsJYc@igxU/gCwo80HhwZduDZAz9hAo9ruNh68Ip/VU1AsuPfmEgHM9s4@FD@ZxHi6yoTgG9LNqDVq@xPdiKJqwwSWK7AT6XpKsrJAQDpNglDwO4qnFocwE6l29wR0nmI2/GaBM/muUaGgQveCynAFLWZPSww@iXZczTamSd6Q0kBcUHTlGiL@9/GsW8MgRyHfVZ3PgO2zfGeYYxykca@cjHQKLlQXECHbe4Ja251uD8jOnAzYUzjRiYoovrXkbUF2@cYB9N8vJxLpeWmIKmy@0NskThGLW@BReXk@MsK76M3pSWs2HuUdCvsbsXAkGcTdJv@HAJjt7bZAVX0cfxtLQCjdVL2IdztjtquZvQ8m4C@XMcpKk/Z9E6/yq2QxSFFUyOE8/OBLoLVizejj2fMma8fAvpLSDZ41hlwpBIY4icnrd7vFBkqMB9A5qSIaSEawbIpQIiwHGFd7R8WTxUL2frPKko34VeAKUCPrBg38@nzQYpvhOHzIJjllOUUkT/JnFuQ6ArJgWxxA4uy3@mwJpCMLTTIvxpWSvPStzOo2KMPrx4xXUk3aq3SreLLz39aW4fV3GrgMpP6iCpPn16gr90gO0MqR/dItftnRnX/PKtVGj7eWsp3DHAs@0Zg8VQXA44kPpL0YQztZ3WzOOx5RQTm7eG@aNGmLRIqQKblXV46bScyqE/m8qYUeGel8lmlshJCvRo8qNC8gCjSdiZQUdFp7po0GiYBTS24PJig4fXm/2ahTU1Je9B1E/eRI2tcERVPDkdDm4b3negSeqVLZTT5TsXs3xHxZRp3GflTdlJe3lHw5RkD8b4czi1hMR0h9A5d6MZfFVASuM7FDK2QsdnnfGcODaBihC/kYJb9Gt6d4wXrXTj5Cy8DqPbsEzX4tcN5kXtl/NXta@LDwyLZ4U2b77Fg8JaMvEhHiqXIVxVfO6H8J4B4boCFEkW8AeflP/Ihn@B6eUPMymcNKRy/K5NSq0YNo3fG@0nXmun2mo1q60nzzaNQN@VpSI2yjI/fd2eP3ZOzkqEDv9O0Nhqci/wERPltvKSGfbka1CfeK3EYMh@z@tz/Fk0xJCaPHr@tLrVFM@0@a9AOCtZz3@38r8)

Next answer must not exceed 1198 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 205b 2022 2428  /\. /+ #\. [ "$(
00000060: 6261 7365 6e61 6d65 2022 2428 7265 6164  basename "$(read
00000070: 6c69 6e6b 202f 7072 6f63 2f24 242f 6578  link /proc/$$/ex
00000080: 6529 2229 2220 3d20 2262 6173 6822 205d  e)")" = "bash" ]
00000090: 2026 2620 6563 686f 2068 7361 6220 7c7c   && echo hsab ||
000000a0: 2065 6368 6f20 6873 7a3c 3c27 454f 4627   echo hsz<<'EOF'
000000b0: 2023 3e3e 5c0a 312b 2f2f 2f5c 0a2f 2a1b   #>>\.1+///\./*.
000000c0: 6767 6347 6d69 561b 5a5a 3b6f 6f6f 226c  ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"l
000000d0: 6f47 223b 3f3d 3025 5321 3131 6f6f 6f3c  oG";?=0%S!11ooo<
000000e0: 223e 3c3e 220a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322  "><>".#define S"
000000f0: 4322 0a23 6966 6465 6620 5f5f 6370 6c75  C".#ifdef __cplu
00000100: 7370 6c75 730a 2066 2829 3b0a 2369 6e63  splus. f();.#inc
00000110: 6c75 6465 3c63 7374 6469 6f3e 0a23 6465  lude<cstdio>.#de
00000120: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 220a 2069 6e74  fine S"++C". int
00000130: 0a23 656e 6469 660a 2369 6664 6566 205f  .#endif.#ifdef _
00000140: 5f4f 424a 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  _OBJC__.#define 
00000150: 5322 432d 6576 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23  S"C-evitcejbO".#
00000160: 656e 6469 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072  endif. main(){pr
00000170: 696e 7466 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829  intf(S)/*/main()
00000180: 7b69 6d70 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469  {import std.stdi
00000190: 6f3b 2244 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b  o;"D".write/**/;
000001a0: 7d2f 2a7d 3c3c 0a20 2272 5422 3b23 7a5f  }/*}<<. "rT";#z_
000001b0: 2242 222c 403e 322b 3b20 203e 2020 2020  "B",@>2+;  >    
000001c0: 5d5b 2076 3b23 3b38 6b2c 3779 322d 3b40  ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@
000001d0: 2c2c 203c 3c3c 0a3e 2242 6566 756e 6765  ,, <<<.>"Befunge
000001e0: 2d39 3622 235e 5a30 3047 235e 5f24 342d  -96"#^Z00G#^_$4-
000001f0: 3e31 2b3e 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c  >1+>,,,,,,,,,,@<
00000200: 0a53 6a71 6f3e 4035 792c 6225 4a61 205b  .Sjqo>@5y,b%Ja [
00000210: 5a61 6f2a 2f2f 2f5d 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281  Zao*///]].......
00000220: b56c 616f 6372 6168 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b  .laocrahC..++++[
00000230: 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b  -<+++++>]<[-<+++
00000240: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e  +++<+++++<+++++>
00000250: 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d  >>]<<<+++++++.>-
00000260: 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b  .>---.<<-----.++
00000270: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d  ++++++.-----.>--
00000280: 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828  .>---.<+.>>>((((
00000290: 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29  ((((((()()()){})
000002a0: 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828  {}){}){}()){})((
000002b0: 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b  ()()()()){}){})[
000002c0: 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29  (([][]){}){}()])
000002d0: 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828  ([]()){})[]())((
000002e0: 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828  [[][]()]([]()(((
000002f0: 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b  (([][][])){}{})[
00000300: 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28 2929 287b 202d  ]){})))[]())({ -
00000310: 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d  }_=")";(!)=seq;m
00000320: 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70  ain|let b!_=""=p
00000330: 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574  utStr$(""!"snret
00000340: 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229 2b2b 226c 6c65  taPgnaB+")++"lle
00000350: 6b73 6148 222d 2d20 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac  ksaH"-- *///....
00000360: 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad  ijome...........
00000370: 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2  Emotinomicon....
00000380: e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839  .........@,ka"89
00000390: 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522                 -egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 3):

## 25. ksh, 884 bytes

Smaller than the previous answer!

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
 f();
#include<cstdio>
#define S"++C"
 int
#endif
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,,<<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@{
Sc0}\Y6m:Hq(Gruz!+*///)]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRrbbtvI9dn8hb6MKW9IWqQoyYnjyJIaX@O0SWzE3m0aWdFS5FBizIvKiy3H6wL9gS7Qp6IPLfpSoEX7UqDPBfop@YL@QXrOzJCiLtldtFViaWbOdc6cORdKQysZf/pUIXuOQyxCR1Y2Cq0XJI1gNon825EfpSSlSUrGVhzSJCHDW/LKo4cf6PuraChVyEHk@9YkoUQ@iBwqEyt0iLwXj7KAhmkik4TaqReFCXGjmAxpmtKY0OmExh4NbSpJtpWSLrGBVvJDYiRsyN5qQ5dUyD51s3BEjSdbUhpl9phMYg8YSyDac8ltlBELdc8F6iSwrihJspjiLoLI8dxbAhrUJrckiUg6BnnpmN4CCSVeaPuZQx0Y4CLxvfBKovY4IkZI5I2GDKpx2tJqE1edKJlf3cLVJAoCarjeFGHS5DYdR@HWwuqLvVfPvtx7djR4/urw6E2nIe3//OLovCNvqDc2Mew2bl2TJdg1MxzxrXCUWSOqanfSGpMnV8jGPJca2WjoZINxghOCA5Nz3NdZGHrhiLDNPGhKa0M4cpDDNtKNsnSSpQJX7PmbmF538YjslDo5m8V1I/SlNTiAdWIHE8LZkBxIHjxYDQCqXTR0KK1xvj@LI9CNY9XICZ06WTBpAXQ6dUiunOtJawtWA2upCzaoNjSt2LVBLr/eUNG3OBPt8ms8Y2aEbu5C9@hE4zSdJC3THHnpOBvW7CgwL@Lb5@lpCM5AzTS@9dIoH1NqBlYCLmzexNYEnDgBDvkBERkvikxkpgIbSzPYIQCcwCFGnIXMvcvAc/QQQIgzuF5mNElN5jP8vRYPlwi67S6g5w7GKFwvGbM39PRF/APAZli2kdq2OfRCEz5XK3MAV92OLL8gEfNisErAV14A@NdeUFxhGNdScIGu6dBrM8x8nzS7DxroG3guAlzmcTp8j8Himhqo7gj1m5KoWLQ5XyMqrzERwLJmLiyWGRcxZCff07BYYbZwh0NvaUuzyLNAxUhgzPX5hqSW5@ONqm49KdMfg7scnp6Tg9OXxPV8WjowHj3KyM8if8WZjiKfHWsS2/l4lfG/DMsbnNyyCTGMJHU6T3ZgkAmEz@/x8ZJlHhtB6nomvgGHfPHzHLa/h0OxvL3EYxhbXuhm9lXBIl@YjZaILuLv2XQaf2bTjKfh@ta8vLEF8vZxdGIJecTYmyOE0CnzjyWmJ1ZyRX2fXWJgxSZLSB8Y/YcV5DSI3nuLx88W@fuqYxciq/uwcmZhZg2TefnGmzJs@aZXq3jRqlW8aDZ85BfMnkxmF0tMyoRHQZR6YRR4dhRiwJtOojglr04PjwZnexcnnUvZzJLY9L2hGQLLAaThzKfJpYwccaXYX8FmblJ7v6zsFbPdVWE7iUVxlyiXYXsS0y5LnF2lyLqY4rDmsDHwRxMaqgpiKFotppajai1Gr9pYRkSxo9pat7PVxPKFz9qN5mOc2aBwCjyUdveBQn2odFzlQeWOI93vKjoNnY6iQO7JFWqbTJW2iWpdhpfhGcs3LRwqrOARCUgQyJdhD3IO8SBbsUyz3u9dPD/tI/4rOk2hpkpuoGwKMqjDUBk6tSlkWcyBLOV3G1tbP@bDzcaW2ai3@KT6sK5pvB6oIbNKJU@xOJMlTLKo6jcJcFMS851J4GUqJdMyRVpFlsRiCPzLrFRmhuYF0qdP15HnEHPTuDMMUhm/Xn9jPCVn78a//OWbp0/rh6R@KI@v@eLbMam@eUTkl@svCfXB/i9PD8j56SGl8fHGfRVevU3TNC8lYlZJBT7gxtHQCsALNlQ8PazTCJg3ss2NDZNOoWDC6mS31W4rR6fHCql0u5dSo8qYmJs/Go3sZ4H31Y/evt2Nokj2o2fy7o879S/O1xsNWGizfCpVHOqC9ck5pEup4rkwJYOBPfGzBP8k4qraLgB40di2IdJ4UbdEVq0CIbhKKlXAKTx3xuR0/ycHg0FZgkGvvdSm74enco4NpasXQpnHra@ea@amKZa8gN0wkFhjUnehnqjdxF5Kzc1Nc/fe3LxvtyW4@xfybuXDQN6X9afdZnWXQFEKr36PXO9Wdneu9Me3TWP3qa63Ab1bDt6Vd2/r9WeVd4ONh0a3Ue3qxevpnXRu1@8vf74dtE5@oT6Lsw/rVTwfrf/x17/71z8//uofvhXZsTU@@Nef2OEZbfyodvvtfFhtl967XYC0BaBa6xrw3zBq7baBr1o1B/Bp18jhgNrtqrOXhv@0u/viP5/lkALWU9Vev9fPcfoaTDmQfQIUwQBg64w1LgAF4DAsxNUE9h0x7gcdWZN31XWtk9Bf7OIZfePTlAzXASB3oN48T@MNVZbX5SSMoeexzqCt2q/KGgRc36dXiXUiwy1BI/77D7/5q/c@CigOPv7@j//@w2//Vg6vMP/7x2//8vHbv3789s9P9StL3nli0FGYuTT8Uv7kxlFAPkCgJdxFNiXhKnhlth9Kbse3gqFjkbDFYmCoK/GwiIGS0xkqmM4up66Lf0rVVZUa677gWitadajMQHys1N5H4JOueqxheD0Gf@/xyKorPBTAgBc4MCj3Pkpfk@wOVNgQF5ME6jX1iX54dPxi7@LoUDde7r0Z/Gz/@cU5rg1eHr0cvDj66uiFXtd4OFL5jmrD7YfQOYI81a7lvFRHq9o1Fy7pWNX0ofLUhC06lGHBXpM09iaq0lE0DXpdqMkM34MmcbqzTQIv9ALLJzTIfCvFFnWhv4XohJ1h0QzfRPFVQsY0pjoG7BsP0iyuYZYBo/rIXgfrxzF2XcNslHAmgOtENAkVzkJwwP4VwtjQGvq3JMSgDk0rhHwICEAx63EZaEz9CQhMxwIDBaRjLyHWEHZosXZRJ5D6SUDzjtZG@0OuIRFkOYg88BHcioQCiyFnAJU9uCVEAil3n@Q2kZhvsT40ivxEOBiZWHHqWb4kMU1KiZV7FsgnLnRwsKtRbAWkQ9zc2QJI8ZDmOqT3ClTpb24/erS1LVZ7zUfbLfirghqqoNX6gCvGkkP9YizFdORhG5YAwp3y/Expkfq0Ua/rRDl/XpocvGGTev34WJfWlEOcomzEO5uND5/nY0Day2kYh/0SyX5Oci9B8Tjiwg@OYfHYgroAME7Lk7flyXl5clZMoAXFBEHjOIrVIBlpzHLo7a589Pr16esWuYPle/go9rwe38uatAYnVKNTL1UbGmcyoukAD2KACV9FTjgAJYWFCwY9tFi/z/p3hgIegNtqCT0USKh2lqJ7ZSHPWI5gooDgBT6k2iENXE2zOGT8FtS5wVIJ1fEjUGZBS2lt7K1aFexUgLbbZEcjVeJHkvT66Nk5OhCeEj9fPD72vs/e4Vj5SXFX4IfbR7qTvRfHSHuXn7HKmbBz0HRSIXsvAHTAQQfzoIMXufuoXNwMdIigfQ7anwftI4g5mpB1EWdC1AkSnc1EFZADhDAnFpIKyCFCDp/PBBWQ/RNJOBIEw8i/ZgV3HOwwq8eBDssj2PkcsLGNZsbAlHhhklqhTVVEhUiCVEAGFLnZenHQZwc/t0ZH/eKghJQVWqAgYMjGq056f@/8CI@0l58gnJdO8tlhPjubg52VYflqCTfngF4OYXCQ@yzX/7zHtTFNskO@IDt9ph67Kvk6pE5uAr4CSMxYHK1DtpiJ@NYZQzCQTsqSpDXsFRAN8xYwqsMQEyZaEYIzbhupEAM5z24V2nXpSmZhAgVGsQ1g4EECiKmdiptJLNuGTIgXVIisdhaY5ro8AGUgkbuuJK2VN1UvdAlwus2m@S4XrvPiZteK7RYUKIs7BQJLchoMLb/hXNdFv9DIA6HkkqRCkJUkFBJSzrb5XVy51p/lmkesHWgvRoMoHoBR0WsX7kcBA/Js4lN@U@hIJ2NvNGZXLMcAgGOlFvd4uAMA0bi5EbVsAYYGLseSVnl/ZfgXOTiHCuaz2C7k9rkQBs6diB0P8yNXxlzMIzs6VO47KbC/mzFp1ZtTlmTKOnAjJfNG0hnofzZV5DvfZakkB@hEZTvLcwLSCdNoZdOVCBg@x@SHz1BzzGX7gR5gG28ESW@HCZulV87yB7lHHkbFMc1dxP/qpIqrXzqm5SMq9sVy7UrnYPl2CQIWagiFgFSoQyBcAfr/z40W07lwqDm7/hCPKpLUKrOWDhAY8xOct8sieHa7uHWW4KXbudJhYC8rIMymAB17YqfCqXL2Yo/5FFr1@vSx25otGJ1crLBfDinzAyW/m6G7iuVnmc58f8ZTIAoWubHm0EGL78HPKfBA48F72x4kY@gnVOhxHQ9bF07pr6oRWH70CwPheGYbDx/ECx4tsqI6BfSyaA9avcb2YCuasMIkie0G@FySrq6QEAyQYpc8DOCqxqHNBehcvsEdJZmPvBmjTfxolmtoELzgsZwCSFmT0cMOo1@WMU@rkXWmN5AUFG85RYm@vP9pFPPKEMh11Gdx4zts3xjnGcZIjDTyjo@BRBNBcQIdd35LWnOtwfkZ04GbC2caMTBFF9e9jKgv3ricfTQR5eNcLi0xBU2X2xtkicIxan0Onl9OjrOs@DJ6U1rOhsKjoF9jdy8EgjibpJ/x4RIcvbfJCq6ij@NpaQUaq5ewD@dsd9RyN6GJbgL5cxykqT9h0Vp8/dohisIKJseJZ2cC3QUrFm/Gnk8ZM16@hfQGkOxxrDJhSKQxRE7P2z1eKDJU4L4BTckQUsIVAwipgAhwXOEdLV/OH5eXs7VIKsqXoRdAqYAPLNh38mmzQYrvwSGz4JjlFKUU0T9LLGwIdMWkIJbYwWXipwmsKQRDOy3Cn5a1RFbidh4VY/ThxSuuI@lWvVW6XXzp0fdze7eKWwVUflgHSfXpo2P8dQNsZ0j96Aa5bu/MuIrLt1Kh7SetpXDHAI@3ZwwWQ3E54EDqL0UTztR2WjOPx5Yzn9i8NRSPGmHSIqUKbFbW4aXTBJVDfzCVMaPCPS@TzSwhSAr0aPKdQkSA0STszKCjolM9b9BomAU0tuDyYoOH15v9goU1NSXvQdQP3kSNrXBEVTw5HQ5uG953oEnqlS0k6MTO85nYUTFlGvdZeVN20p7oaJiS7MEYfw6nlpCY7hA65240g68KSGl8i0LGVuj4rDOeE8cmUBHid01wi35Kb4/wopVunJyFV2F0E5bpWvy6wbyo/QR/Vfu0@MCweFZo8@Y7f1BYSyY@xEPlMoSris/9EN4zIFxXgCLJAv7gk/If1vAvLT3xMJPCSUMqx2/RpNSKYdPAWN5LvNZOtdVqVlsPH28agb4rS0VslGV@@ro9f@ycnJUIHf5tn7HV5F7gIybKbYmSGfbka1CfeK3EYMh@z@tz/Fk0xJCafPHkUXWrmT/T5r/84KxkXfxW5T8)

Next answer must not exceed 1149 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b67 6763 476d  .1+///\./*.ggcGm
000000a0: 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f  iV.ZZ;ooo"loG";?
000000b0: 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22  =0%S!11ooo<"><>"
000000c0: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 220a 2369  .#define S"C".#i
000000d0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
000000e0: 0a20 6628 293b 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c  . f();.#include<
000000f0: 6373 7464 696f 3e0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  cstdio>.#define 
00000100: 5322 2b2b 4322 0a20 696e 740a 2365 6e64  S"++C". int.#end
00000110: 6966 0a23 6966 6465 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43  if.#ifdef __OBJC
00000120: 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 2d65  __.#define S"C-e
00000130: 7669 7463 656a 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966  vitcejbO".#endif
00000140: 0a20 6d61 696e 2829 7b70 7269 6e74 6628  . main(){printf(
00000150: 5329 2f2a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 696d 706f  S)/*/main(){impo
00000160: 7274 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422  rt std.stdio;"D"
00000170: 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 7d3c  .write/**/;}/*}<
00000180: 3c0a 2022 7254 223b 237a 5f22 4222 2c40  <. "rT";#z_"B",@
00000190: 3e32 2b3b 2020 3e20 2020 205d 5b20 763b  >2+;  >    ][ v;
000001a0: 233b 386b 2c37 7932 2d3b 402c 2c3c 3c3c  #;8k,7y2-;@,,<<<
000001b0: 0a3e 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3622 235e  .>"Befunge-96"#^
000001c0: 5a30 3047 235e 5f24 342d 3e31 2b3e 2c2c  Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,
000001d0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 407b 0a53 6330 7d5c  ,,,,,,,,@{.Sc0}\
000001e0: 5936 6d3a 4871 2847 7275 7a21 2b2a 2f2f  Y6m:Hq(Gruz!+*//
000001f0: 2f29 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372  /)]........laocr
00000200: 6168 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  ahC..++++[-<++++
00000210: 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  +>]<[-<++++++<++
00000220: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c  +++<+++++>>>]<<<
00000230: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
00000240: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
00000250: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
00000260: 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  <+.>>>((((((((((
00000270: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29  ()()()){}){}){})
00000280: 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829  {}()){})((()()()
00000290: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d  ()){}){})[(([][]
000002a0: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929  ){}){}()])([]())
000002b0: 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28  {})[]())(([[][](
000002c0: 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d  )]([]()((((([][]
000002d0: 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929  [])){}{})[]){}))
000002e0: 295b 5d28 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922  )[]())({ -}_=")"
000002f0: 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65  ;(!)=seq;main|le
00000300: 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224  t b!_=""=putStr$
00000310: 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61  (""!"snrettaPgna
00000320: 422b 2229 2b2b 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 222d  B+")++"lleksaH"-
00000330: 2d20 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0  - *///....ijome.
00000340: 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e  ..........Emotin
00000350: 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac  omicon..........
00000360: e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  ...@,ka"89-egnuf
00000370: 656e 5522                                enU"
```

Answer (score 3):

## 27. Trefunge-97, 912 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
 f();
#include<cstdio>
#define S"++C"
 int
#endif
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}
   @,,"rT",,,,,,,,,+1_;#:< v+;#!<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>5k$2+;>   [$v;#;8k,7y2-;@,,<<
>"Befunge-96"#^000G #^_$$3->,,,,,,,,,,@
Sc0]PM4zeFe{;fi646*///}]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbcttIds/CL@xLC@QYgAgQJGXLMm9rXW0ntqWyNLOOKZoLAg0SFi4MLhJljbYqP5CpylMqD9nKS6qS2rykKs@p2k/xF@wfOOd0N0Dw4pmpJLRFdve5dZ9z@lxAjq1k@vVrhRw4DrEInVjZJLRekzSC2Szy7yZ@lJKUJimZWnFIk4SM78hbjx5/pp@uo7FUIUeR71uzhBL5KHKoTKzQIfJBPMkCGqaJTBJqp14UJsSNYjKmaUpjQuczGns0tKkk2VZK@sQGWskPiZGwIXurj11SIYfUzcIJNZ7tSmmU2VMyiz1gLIFozyV3UUYs3HsuUCeBdU1JksUUTxFEjufeEdhBfXZHkoikU5CXTukdkFDihbafOdSBAS4S3wuvJWpPI2KERK42Zdgapy2ttnDViZLl1V1cTaIgoIbrzREmze7SaRTurqy@Pnj74vuDFyejV2@PT973mtLh31yeXPTkqnprE8Pu4tE1WYJTM8UR3wonmTWhqnYvbTF5coVUl7nUSbWpkyrjBBYCg8k57rssDL1wQthhHrWkrTGYHOSwg/SjLJ1lqcAVZ/4xpjd9NJGdUidns7puhL60BQbYJnYwI5wNyYHk0aPNAKDqoKJDaYvz/V0cwd44Vp28pHMnC2ZtgM7nDsk353rS1orWQFvqig5qTU0rTm2Qq99XVfQtzkS7@j3amCmhn7vQAzrRNE1nSds0J146zcZ1OwrMy/juVXoWgjNQM43vvDTKx5SagZWAC5u3sTUDJ06AQ24gIuNFkYnMtsDG0gJ2DAAncIgRZyFz7zLwAj0EEOIMrpcZzVKT@Qx/r8fjNYJ@tw/ouYMxCtdLpuwNPX0V/wiwGZZtpLZtjr3QhM/NmzmCq25Hll@QiHkx2CTgBy8A/BsvKK4wjOspuEDfdOiNGWa@T1r9R030DbSLAJd5nI0/YbC4oQZud4L7m5OoWLQ5XyMqrzERwLJuriyWGRcxZD8/07hYYbpwx2Nv7UiLyLNCxUhgzPfzI0ktz8cbVdt9VqY/BXc5PrsgR2dviOv5tGQwHj3KyC8if4NNJ5HPzJrEdj7epPzvw/IBZ3dsQgwjSZ3es30YZALh22d8uqaZp0aQup6Jb8AhX/w2h71f4FAs763xGMeWF7qZfV2wyBcWozWiy/gXDp3G3zg042m4vrUsb2qBvEMcvbSEPGIcLBFC6JT5xxrTl1ZyTX2fXWJgxSZrSJ8Z/ecN5DSIPnmr5meL/H2T2YXI2iGsnFuYWcNkWb7xvgxbv@m1Gl60Wg0vmg0f@QWzZ7PFxRKTMuFJEKVeGAWeHYUY8OazKE7J27Pjk9H5weXL3pVsZkls@t7YDIHlCNJw5tPkSkaOuFKcr2CzNKl/Wt/sNdPd9QbdOdwsziazLLzkV3v4mudILF@4RLkKu7OY9lmK7itFfsdkitWNjSkmmtFQVRBD0eoxtRxVazN61caCJYod1db6vd0WFkp81m22nuLMBtWkwEPp9h9VFepDUeUqjyr3HOuho@g0dHqKAmku31HXZHvpmrivq/AqPGeprY1DhdVWItcJAvkqHEB6Ix4kRpbUtoeDy1dnQ8R/S@cplG/JLVRoQQYlH@6Gzm0KCR3TLasu@s3d3d/y4U5z12w22nxSe9zQNF561JFZpZJnc5zJEuZz3OqPCXBTEvOjSeBlKiXdso20i4SMdRe4slmpLDTNa7GvX28izyHmjnFvGKQyfbf93nhOzj9O//CH98@fN45J41ie3vDFD1NSe/@EyG@23xDqgwHenB2Ri7NjSuPT6kMNXoMd0zSvJGLWSAU@4HLT0ArAdaoqmg9LQgLqjWyzWjXpHGozLIQ67W5XOTk7VUil37@SmjXGxNz5zWRivwi8H37z4UMniiLZj17Ind/2Gt9dbDebsNBlqVuqONQF7ZMLyMxSxXNhSkYje@ZnCf5JxFW1DgB4fdq1Iah5Ub9EVqsBIfhKKlXAKTx3weTs8K@ORqOyBIPeeKlNP43P5BwbqmQvhIqSa1@90MwdUyx5AbvMILHOpHagdKnfxl5KzZ0ds/Ng7jxIYLrnui7Hl7Kev2rNUafS7pKbWqey3ZUIAjuVzyP5UNaf959cV1u1Th/oBtWbTqWzf60/vWsZHeDS7Ur9chapfGw0Gi9I5eOoWt01@oUA/bl0YTeG528ef6an9L7jenuP99B2D8Mvf/9Pf/7vL3/3X74V2bE1PfrzvzLDGl38qPWH3XxY65be@32AdAWgVu8b8N8w6t2uga96LQfwad/I4YDa76uLl4b/tPuH4j@f5ZACNlDVwXAwzHGGGkw5kH0CFMEAYOuMNS4ABeAwLMTVBPY9MR5GPVmTO@q21kvo33bQfj/6NCXjbQDIPSh7L9K4qsrytpyEMbRe1jl0d4c1WYO47/v0OrFeynCDUIl/@eM//Mn7FAUUB1/@@V/@8sd//I9ylIf5f3756d@//PSnLz/923P92pL3nxl0EmYuDb@Xv7pxFJDPEO8Jd58dSbgRXqe9x5Lb861g7FgkbLMAGepKPC4CpOT0xgpm1au56@KfUnNVpc6aQLjyilYbKwsQHyv1TxH4q6ueahh7T@EuDHjY1RUeJmDA6ywYlFswZahJdg8KfYiZSQJlo/pMPz45fX1weXKsG28O3o9@d/jq8gLXRm9O3oxen/xw8lpvaDxUqfxE9fHeY2hgQZ5q13NeqqPV7LoLF3iqavpYeW7CER3KsOCsSRp7M1XpKZoGLTeUhobvQa86398jgRd6geUTGmS@lWKnvNJmQ@TCBrXoyW@j@DohUxpTHYP5rQfZHtcwBYFSfWSvg/bjGJu/cTZJOBPAdSKahApnIThgGw0hbmyN/TsSYsCH3hnSAQQLoFi02gw0pf4MBKZTgYEC0qmXEGsMJ7RY16oTqEBIQPPG2kb9Qx4iEaRAiErwEdyJZAOLIWcADQa4JcQBKXef5C6RmG@xdjiK/EQ4GJlZcepZviSxnZSyLvcskE9caCThVJPYCkiPuLmzBVBpQArskcFb2MpwZ@/Jk909sTpoPdlrw18NtqEKWm0IuGIsOdQvxlJMJx52gwkg3CuvzpU2acybjYZOlItXpcnRezZpNE5PdWlLOcYpyka888X4@FU@BqSDnIZxOCyRHOYkDxLUsBMu/OgUFk8tqBkA46w8@VCeXJQn58UEOmFMHjSOo1gNkonGNIfe7son796dvWuTe1h@gI/izNvxg6xJW2ChOp17qdrUOJMJTUdoiBEWAypywgFsUmi4YDBAjQ2H7DECQwEPwGO1xT4USLZ2lqJ7ZSHPZo5gooDgFT6k1iNNXE2zOGT8VrZzi2UUbsePYDMru5S2pt6mVcFOBWi3S/Y1UiN@JEnvTl5coAOhlbh90Xzs/ZC9g1m5pbgrcOMOke7lwetTpL3PbaxyJswOmk4q5OA1gI446GgZdPQ6dx@Vi1uAjhF0yEGHy6BDBDFHE7Iu40yIeolE5wtRBeQIIcyJhaQCcoyQ41cLQQXk8KUkHAmCYeTfsLo/DvaZ1uNAh@UJnHwJ2NxDNWNgSrwwSa3QpiqiQiRBKiADilxtgzgYMsMvrdHJsDCUkLJhFygIGLLxJksfHlycoEkHuQXBXjrJZ8f57HwJdl6G5asl3JwDejmEwVHus3z/FwO@G9Mk@@Q7sj9k22NXJV@H1MlVwFcAiSmLo/XILlMRPzpjCArSSVmStIV9BKJh3gJGDRhiwkQtQnDGYyMVYiDnxa1Cva5dySxMoMAojgEMPEgAMbVTcTOJZduQCfGCCpG13grTfC@PYDOQyF1XkrbKh2oUewlwusem@SlXrvPqYbeK4xYUKIs7BQJLcpoMLb/hfK@rfqGRR2KTa5IKQVaSUEhIOdvWz3Hlu/4m1zxi7UPrMRlF8QiUil67cj8KGJBnM5/ym0InOpl6kym7YjkGABwrtbjHwx0AiMbVjahlDTA0cDmWtMrnK8O/y8E5VDBfxHYhd8iFMHDuRMw8zI9cGXMxj@zoULnvpMD@fsGk3WjNWZIp74ErKVlWks5A/2dVRb7zc5pKcoBOVHayPCcgnVCNVlZdiYDhc0xufIaaY67rD/YBuvEmkPT2mbBFeuUsf5V75GFUmGnpIv6vLFVc/ZKZ1k1UnIvl2o3OwfLtGgQ01BQbAlKxHQLhCtD//9xoNZ0Lh1rS66/xqCJJbVJryYDAmFtwWS@r4MXt4tpZg5du50aHgbNsgDCdAnTqiZMKp8rZizPmU9IHIU/d9mLB6OVihf5ySJkfbPLnGbqbWH6T6cL3FzwFomCRK2sJHXbxC/g5BRo0Hn2y7VEyhX5ChR7X8bB14ZT@phqB5Ue/UBCOF7rx8PsAwaNNNlSngF4W7UGr19wb7UYzVpgksd0En0vSzRUSggFSnJKHAVzVOLS1Al3KN3iiJPORN2O0gx@tcg0Nglc8llMAKWsyBthhDMsylmk1ss32DSQFxQdOUaIvn38exbwyBHId97N68H12bozzDGMiRhr5yMdAoomgOIOOO78l7aXW4OKc7YGrC2caMTBFF9e9jKiv3ricfTQT5eNSLi0xhZ2utzfIEoVj1PoWPL@cHGd94@voLWk9GwqPgn6N3b0QCOJsln7Dh0tw9N4WK7iKPo6npQ1orF7CPpyz3VfL3YQmugnkz3GQpvGMRWvxLXCPKAormBwnXtgEugtWLN5OPZ8yZrx8C@ktINnTWGXCkEhjiJyet3u8UGSowL0KTckYUsI1AwipgAhwXOEdLV/OH6WXs7VIKsr3oRdAqYAPLNhPA9JWkxRfx0NmwTHLKUopon@TWOgQ6IpJQSwxw2XiFxKsKQRFO23Cn5a1RVbiep4UY/Th1SuuI@luo126XXzpyS9z@7iJWwW2/LgBkhrzJ6f4Iws4zpj60S1y3dtfcBWXb@OG9p6118IdAzzdWzBYDcXlgAOpvxRNOFPbaS88HlvOfGLz1lA8aoRJm5QqsEVZh5dOE1QO/dVUxoIKz7xOttCEICnQo9nPChEBRpOwM4OOis71vEGjYRbQ2ILLiw0eXm/2QxrW1JS8B1E/ezM1tsIJVdFyOhhuD973oUkalDUk6MTJ85k4UTFlOx6y8qbspAPR0bBNsgdj/DmcWkJie4fQuXSjGXxTQErjOxQytULHZ53xkjg2gYoQv4eCW/TX9O4EL1rpxslZeB1Gt2GZrs2vG8yL2k/wV7Wvqw8Mi2eFNm@@8weF9WTmQzxUrkK4qvjcD@EDA8J1BSiSLOAPPin/fQ//7tQTDzMpWBpSOX7DJqVWDIcGxvJB4rX3a@12q9Z@/HTHCPSOLBWxUZa59XV72eycnJUIPf5NoLHb4l7gIybKbYuSGc7ka1CfeO3EYMj@wBty/EU0xJCafPfsSW23lT/T5j9A4axkXfxk5n8A)

Next answer must not exceed 1185 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b67 6763 476d  .1+///\./*.ggcGm
000000a0: 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f  iV.ZZ;ooo"loG";?
000000b0: 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22  =0%S!11ooo<"><>"
000000c0: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 220a 2369  .#define S"C".#i
000000d0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
000000e0: 0a20 6628 293b 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c  . f();.#include<
000000f0: 6373 7464 696f 3e0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  cstdio>.#define 
00000100: 5322 2b2b 4322 0a20 696e 740a 2365 6e64  S"++C". int.#end
00000110: 6966 0a23 6966 6465 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43  if.#ifdef __OBJC
00000120: 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 2d65  __.#define S"C-e
00000130: 7669 7463 656a 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966  vitcejbO".#endif
00000140: 0a20 6d61 696e 2829 7b70 7269 6e74 6628  . main(){printf(
00000150: 5329 2f2a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 696d 706f  S)/*/main(){impo
00000160: 7274 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422  rt std.stdio;"D"
00000170: 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 7d0a  .write/**/;}/*}.
00000180: 2020 2040 2c2c 2272 5422 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c     @,,"rT",,,,,,
00000190: 2c2c 2c2b 315f 3b23 3a3c 2076 2b3b 2321  ,,,+1_;#:< v+;#!
000001a0: 3c0a 2022 7254 223b 237a 5f22 4222 2c40  <. "rT";#z_"B",@
000001b0: 3e35 6b24 322b 3b3e 2020 205b 2476 3b23  >5k$2+;>   [$v;#
000001c0: 3b38 6b2c 3779 322d 3b40 2c2c 3c3c 0a3e  ;8k,7y2-;@,,<<.>
000001d0: 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3622 235e 3030  "Befunge-96"#^00
000001e0: 3047 2023 5e5f 2424 332d 3e2c 2c2c 2c2c  0G #^_$$3->,,,,,
000001f0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 0a53 6330 5d50 4d34 7a65  ,,,,,@.Sc0]PM4ze
00000200: 4665 7b3b 6669 3634 362a 2f2f 2f7d 5de2  Fe{;fi646*///}].
00000210: 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372 6168 43c2  .......laocrahC.
00000220: a62b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c  .++++[-<+++++>]<
00000230: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c  [-<++++++<+++++<
00000240: 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b  +++++>>>]<<<++++
00000250: 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d  +++.>-.>---.<<--
00000260: 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d  ---.++++++++.---
00000270: 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e  --.>--.>---.<+.>
00000280: 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829  >>((((((((((()()
00000290: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829  ()){}){}){}){}()
000002a0: 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b  ){})((()()()()){
000002b0: 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29  }){})[(([][]){})
000002c0: 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b  {}()])([]()){})[
000002d0: 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b  ]())(([[][]()]([
000002e0: 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929  ]()((((([][][]))
000002f0: 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28  {}{})[]){})))[](
00000300: 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129  ))({ -}_=")";(!)
00000310: 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221  =seq;main|let b!
00000320: 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221  _=""=putStr$(""!
00000330: 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229  "snrettaPgnaB+")
00000340: 2b2b 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 222d 2d20 2a2f  ++"lleksaH"-- */
00000350: 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2  //....ijome.....
00000360: 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963  ......Emotinomic
00000370: 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940  on.............@
00000380: 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522  ,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 3):

## 33. Sexefunge-97, 1644 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_1000000G$!v
                                ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
.l        .       *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//TJrf$8AlzKx5?x?I-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbbhvJlc/qX8hLqalxd4tsNinZskSRHN1tJ7alWJqJ1xTNNLuLZFt9YfoiUdYoGGyAAQIsdoI8DII87GCA3cVesg8ZZB4WO0/O@/gf9APJHzjnVFU3mxfbs7NLic2qOtc651SdU0V2zWjw5k2BbNs2MQntm0nfNx@SOIDeMHAv@24Qk5hGMRmYoU@jiHQvyWOH7r2kL86CrlQgu4HrmsOIEnk3sKlMTN8m8nbYTzzqx5FMImrFTuBHpBeEpEvjmIaEjoY0dKhvUUmyzJg0iQW0kusTPWJN9ih3e6RAdmgv8ftU31iV4iCxBmQYOsBYAtFOj1wGCTFR91RgiXjmGSVRElKchRfYTu@SgAbl4SWJAhIPQF48oJdAQonjW25iUxsaOEhcxz@TqDUIiO4Teakqg2qcNje6gqN2EE2OruJoFHge1XvOCGHS8DIeBP7q1OjD7cf3Ptq@t9958Hhv/2mjKu383cn@cUNeUi8solt1nLomSzBrZjjimn4/MftU1a6kBSZPLpClSS5lslQtkSXGCTwEDpNT3CeJ7zt@n7DJ3FqRFrrgcpDDJtIMkniYxAJXzPmTkJ430UVWTO2UzfS47rvSAjhgkVjekHA2JAWSW7fmA4BqEw3tSwuc78/CAHTjWGVyn47sxBvWADoa2SRVrudIC1NWA2upUzYoVjUtm7VOTn@@pGJscSba6c/Rx8wIzTSErjGIBnE8jGqG0XfiQdItW4FnnISXD@JDH4KBGnF46cRB2qbU8MwIQti4CM0hBHEEHFIHERkXikxkpgJrS2PYHgBszyZ6mPgsvPPAY4wQQAgTWF5GMIwNFjP8WQ67MwTNehPQ0wBjFD0nGrAHRvo0/i5gMyxLjy3L6Dq@AZ/zldmFpW4FppuRiH7WmCfgY8cD/HPHy5YwtMsxhEDTsOm54SeuS1aat6oYG@gXAc7zOOy@wM3inOqobh/1G5EgG7Q4Xz3IjzERwLJsTA3mGWd7yHo6p242wmzR63admSmNd54pKkYCba7PJyQ2HRdXVHF1I09/AOGyd3hMdg8fkZ7j0pzD@O6RR74XuHN82g9c5tYotNL2PON/5OcnOLxkHaLrUWw3NtahkQiEt8/x7oxl7upe3HMMfACHdPDtHNbewyEbXpvh0Q1Nx@8l1lnGIh0Yt2aITsL3TDoO3zJpxlPvueakvIEJ8nawdd8U8oi@PUEIW6fMP2aY3jejM@q6bBEDK9aZQXrJ6F/OIade8MKZdj8b5M95bhciizswcmRiZvWjSfn60zxsdqUXi7jQikVcaBZ8pAvMGg7HC0t08oT7XhA7fuA5VuDjhjcaBmFMHh/u7XeOtk/uN05lI4lCw3W6hg8sO5CGE5dGpzJyxJFsfhmbiU75xayyZ8x2Z3NsZ3O32PPcMo6S7x3h74icbdexJvdpE0cMSCc0HIYUnvN2658mpv1D9PjFmG6G58ZGymdjw4AMT@NLfM6Rjcr9ENkZ3QzP6NLrBjBxkl@4XuAHInd1e/gu0xEnnZcCGDar8gBrIhVC/3@vbZRSCV0lluJ7RDn16@CXJquqmkpWkmH9gwWphVVBMKS@qiCGopVDatqqVmP0qoU1ZhDaqqU1G6srWNvyXr26chd7FkRzDDyUevPWkkJdqIN7yq3CFce63lRK1LcbigKVSapR3WC61A3U69Q/9Y9YNVLDpsLKYVGeCAL51G9BRUIcqGVYHbLYbp08OGwj/mM6iqHiji6gqPYSqNJRGzqyKNRgWCGxgrBZXV39kDeXq6tGtVLjneLtiqbxarGMzAqFtADDnixhCYaqfhIBNyUynhsEXoaSsy1TpJbVUFgqw@5jFApjS/Py@c2b88CxibGsX@k6KQyeLD7Vt8jR88Evf/l0a6uyRyp78uCcDz4bkOLTO0R@tPiIUBcc8Ohwlxwf7lEaHixdF@HVWjYM41QiRpEU4AP2Y@qbHgTPkoruwyqegHkDy1haMiAyNFa7btbqdWX/8EAhhWbzVKoWgQmZeR2eSsYy@VG/b93znI9/9OzZZhAEshvckzc/bFQ@OF6sVmGgziowqWDTHi66Yyyw@MswtqWC0wMA6XSsoZtE@DYMVyI9VdvMizIMB1D5EaRuQd5ygqZhWDmuxSLwNQwqQYjFeXVBNASW08uGTstjqYc7P97tdPLK6fTciS36onuYEkpwTnJ8OFNwZ6rHmrFsiCHHY9s5KFRmSm1C8Vq@CJ2YGsvLxua1sXxdl5qEnEsbGxuEv8dNbJ3Xm9I5IWCicY4upa@7l6v6OWNQeH7vfMYBWyV5R@7Axg0UWxIMnNdbHbmdq8aaGavSVh0xmoV6vg5pkufnS/cqlSrqwNDkuxs67ftJj@7IpDPrdK4O51jgQzma8ETunMOZC1hWqjAz8s5XvVkFvMq9pXOOWNgqTby2CjnOtpn8VO4wAiRZPH8Pc1RyTB77DpJP7pmT8rYKUtlNacviE5fP1XX75h9//5dv//XVf7tmYIXmYPfVf9588fWr7O/mH/7@5rN/@@6P8Pjzl/AYj9189hsY@fU/33zx7c1nv2XP39z8@l@wzeCvf4VN8c@Ix73Xn@Z6YuzVV3/@8tVXWfe7P80hZHjfTFK9/gyxvwGWTOwkG4HyKSjzxdcpwutfvfpGoEDvuz@O268/hTYgsv@JJmMAyH9iAtNxPvYNTv6Lb1999ep/2Mak1/Gj2GzX02axnns2mwCpC0Cx3NThX9fL9bqOr3IxBfBuU0/hgNpsquOXhn/a1XX2z3spJIO1VLXVbrVTnLYGXQ5knwBFMADYOGONA0ABOAwLcTWBfUX0605D1uRNdVFrRPQXm7hhfOLSmHQXASA34KR9HIdLqiwvypEP9VBsHvV9c6coa8Wi4zux7Lr0LDLvq/KVLhnGyY/D3tL6tvvyJ6M7H44@fKBf67qG0fnXL3/7B@dF4FFs3PzTV3/98nf/lS86of/1zef/cfP5H24@//et0pkpr6eLwv9IftMLA4@8hPKT8L1sWRJ7GqaKtdtSr@GaXtc2iV9jyd8vKWE3S/6S3egqWOSfjno9fCvFnqqUWbUC6UzRil1lDOJtpfwigM2zpx5oWFccwIbd4iVFSeEpEBr82AeN/I2Q0tYkq2EFHtQDUQSnWHWjtLd/8HD7ZH@vpD/aftr52c6Dk2Mc6zzaf9R5uP/x/sNSReNpWOUzKnfXblMf5alWOeWl2lrRKvcg/QxUrdRVtgyYok0ZFsw1ikNnqCoNRdPeFAicVHXXOaNktL5GPPCVZ7qEeolrxnhxN3XrB1kZ78uyK8KLIDyLyICGtISFyoUDpR6OYXkFRnWRfQmsH4Z4F9VN@hFnArh2QCNf4SwEB7zVg/TdNbvuJfGxmIkDKGtiyFxAMb75Y6ABdYcgMB4IDBQQD5yImF2Yocku0UoEDkTEo@k9n4X2hxqLBFDeQYqED@9SFFIw6HMG1sCEcIVtVUrDJ7qMJBZb7HYuCNxIBBgZmmHsmK4kMU1yFSWPLJBPejVpAWbVD02PNEgvDTYPDj5Q3jVI6zGo0l5eu3NndU2MtlburNXgXQQ1VEGrtQFXtCWbullbCmnfwcupCBCulAdHSo1URpBbSkQ5fpDr7D5lnUrl4KAkLSh72EXZiHc0bu89SNuAtJ3SMA47OZKdlORagiN1nwvfPYDBAxPqYcA4zHee5TvH@c5R1rmWJKxkaBgGoepFfY1ZDqO9J@8/eXL4pEauYPgaPrI5L4bXsiYtgIfgROHEalXjTPo07qAjOljoqsgJG6CksHDGoIUWa7fZrSZDgQjAadWEHgokWSuJMbwSn5dWtmCigOApPqTYIFUcjZPQZ/ym1LnAIwKq4wagzJSW0sLAmTcq2KkArdfJukaKxA0k6cn@vWMMIPQS9y@6jz132BPcyj3FQ4E7t41097cfHiDtVepjlTNhftBKpEC2HwJol4N2J0G7D9PwUbm4MWgPQTsctDMJ2kEQCzQh6yRMhKj7SHQ0FpVBdhHCglhIyiB7CNl7MBaUQXbuSyKQYDMM3HN2DRF668zqoVeC4T7MfAJYXUMz48YUOX4Um75FVUSFnQSpgAwoUrO1Qq/NHD8xRvvtzFFCyhwtUBAwZO15nt7ZPt5Hl7ZSD4K/SiTt7aW9ownYUR6WjuZwUw4Y5bANdtKY5foft7g2cKZYJx@Q9TZTjy2VdBxSJzcBHwEkZiyO1iCrzER86owhGKhE8pKkBTwjIxrmLWBUgSYmTLQibM44baRCDOQ8XlVo15klmfgRFB/ZNICBAwkgpFYsViYxLQsyIS5QIbLYmGKa6nILlIFE3utJ0kJ@UpVMFw@7a6ybznJqOU9PdiGbbkaBsnhQIDAnp8rQ0hXOdZ2OC43cEkrOSMoEmVFEISGlbFfexZVr/Vau6Y61DsfqficIO2BUjNqp9ZHBgDwZupSvFNovkYHTH7AllmIAwDZjk0c8rAGAaNzciJq3AEODkGNJKz@/PPyDFJxCBfPx3i7ktrkQBk6DiLmHxVFPxlzMd3YMqDR2YmB/NWZSq6yMWJLJ68CNFE0aqcRA/2dTBa79LktFKaBEVDazNCcgnTCNljddjoDhc0zufIaaYs7aD/QA2zh9SHrrTNg4vXKW3ys80m1UuGliIf4gT2VLP@emWRdl82K5dm5wsHw7AwELVYVCQCrUIbBdAfr/XxhNp3MRUBN2/T4RlSWpeWbNORAYcw9O2mUaPF5d3Doz8NzqnBswMJc5EGZTgA4cMVMRVCl7Mce0S5og5G6vNh7QG6lYYb8UkucHSr6bYW8ey7cyHcf@mKdAFCxSY02ggxbvwU8p0KFh54VldaIBnCdUOOPaDh5dOKU7r0Zg@dHNDITtsW0c/HpS8KiROdUpoOdFO3DUq651VoMhK0yi0KpCzEXx/AoJwQDJZsm3ARzVOHRlCjqRb3BGUeIib8ZoGT9W8jU0CJ6KWE4BpOyQ0cITRjsvY5JWI4tMbyDJKJ5xihx9fv6jIOSVIZCXUJ/pia@zeeM@zzD6oqWR57wNJJrYFIdw4k5XSW3iaHB8xHTg5sKeRnRM0dlyzyOWpldcyj4YivJxIpfmmIKms8cbZInCcdd6GzxdnBxnVvFZ9BVpNhuKiILzGlt7@OVYmAzjt8RwDo7Ru8IKruwcx9PSHDRWL@E5nLNdV/OnCU2cJpA/x0GaygbbrcWPUhpEUVjBZNvh2CdwumDF4sXAcSljxss3n14AkjUIVSYMiTSGyOn5cY8XigwVuC/BoaQLKeGMAYRUQAQ4jvATLR9OvybKZ2uRVJSPfMeDUgEvLNgvleKVKsl@HQSZBdsspyi5Hf2txMKGQJd1MmKJOS4RP9hih0IwtF0j/LasJrISt3M/a2MMTy/xEpKuVmq51cWH7ryf2/N53Aqg8u0KSKqM7hzgb75gOl3qBhfIdW19zFUsvrkKrW3UZrY7Bri7NmYwvRXnNxxI/bndhDO17No44vHImXYsfjQUV43QqZFcBTYu63DRaYLKpt@bSh9T4ZxnycaWECQZejB8pxCxwWgSnszgREVHpfSARv3Eo6EJixcPeLi82e/62KEmFz2I@tIZqqHp96mKniuB49bguQ6HpFbeQoJOzDztiRllXaZxm5U3@SBtiRMNU5JdjPF7ODWHxHSHrXNiRTP4vA0pDi9RyMD0bZedjCfEsQ5UhPgdK6yin9DLfVxouRUnJ/6ZH1z4eboaX27Qz2o/wV/V3kxfGGZ3hRY/fKcXheVo6MJ@qJz6sFTx3g/hLR226wJQRInHLz4p/7kh/@LdEZeZFDwNqRy/PZZiM4RJA2N5O3Jq68VabaVYu313WfdKm7KU7Y2yzL1fsibdzslZidDg33Lrqys8ClzERLk1UTLDnFwN6hOnFukM2W05bY4/3g1xS40@2LhTXF1J77T57@E4K7kkfsH3Nw)

Next answer must not exceed 2137 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020  .>  #^Gv        
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22           @,"B"_"
00000230: 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d  Tr",,@.   v<[_"]
00000240: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c  Befunge-93">,,,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,,,@<.   >#<"
00000260: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
00000270: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
00000280: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
000002a0: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
000002b0: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
000002c0: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
000002f0: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000300: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000310: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030  gnuferdauQ"_1000
00000320: 3030 3047 2421 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020  000G$!v.        
00000330: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000340: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d 6567          ,,"79-eg
00000350: 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f22 5365 7865  nufetniuQ"_"Sexe
00000360: 6675 6e67 652d 3937 2223 402c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-97"#@,,,,,
00000370: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 230a 2e6c 2020 2020  ,,,,,,,@#..l    
00000380: 2020 2020 2e20 2020 2020 2020 2a2f 2f2f      .       *///
00000390: 7b7d 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372  {}]........laocr
000003a0: 6168 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  ahC.............
000003b0: c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2  ................
000003c0: 86a8 c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3  ................
000003d0: 9fe2 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690  ................
000003e0: e289 a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286  ................
000003f0: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2  ................
00000400: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000410: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f  ................
00000420: c2a1 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692  ................
00000430: e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000440: 92e2 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000450: 86a8 c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82  ................
00000460: e286 a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000470: 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c  ................
00000480: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2  ................
00000490: 86a8 c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
000004a0: cf80 c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2  ................
000004b0: 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2  ................
000004c0: a1ce b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
000004d0: e296 b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2  ................
000004e0: bb2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c  .++++[-<+++++>]<
000004f0: 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c  [-<++++++<+++++<
00000500: 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b  +++++>>>]<<<++++
00000510: 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d  +++.>-.>---.<<--
00000520: 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d  ---.++++++++.---
00000530: 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e  --.>--.>---.<+.>
00000540: 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829  >>((((((((((()()
00000550: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829  ()){}){}){}){}()
00000560: 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b  ){})((()()()()){
00000570: 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29  }){})[(([][]){})
00000580: 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b  {}()])([]()){})[
00000590: 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b  ]())(([[][]()]([
000005a0: 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929  ]()((((([][][]))
000005b0: 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28  {}{})[]){})))[](
000005c0: 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129  ))({ -}_=")";(!)
000005d0: 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221  =seq;main|let b!
000005e0: 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221  _=""=putStr$(""!
000005f0: 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229  "snrettaPgnaB+")
00000600: 2b2b 696e 6974 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 2822  ++init"lleksaH("
00000610: 7b2d 0a2f 2f54 4a72 6624 3841 6c7a 4b78  {-.//TJrf$8AlzKx
00000620: 353f 783f 492d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f 2f2f f09f  5?x?I-}--)*///..
00000630: 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f  ..ijome.........
00000640: 98ad 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f  ..Emotinomicon..
00000650: 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122  ...........@,ka"
00000660: 3839 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522            89-egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 3):

## 35. Septefunge-97, 2170 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
 red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left
.y          .     *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//ner"4@Rl4Sz5L3ZI-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbbhvJlc/qX8hLqakxu0U2m5RsWaJIRnfbWdtSLM/Ea4lmmt3VZFt9YfoiidYoGGyAAQIsdoI8DBb7sIMBdhd7yT5kkHlY7Dw57zP/oB/Y/IH3nKrqCy/2OJNQUrPq3OucU1WnSt03ouGbNyWybVnEIHRgJAPfeEjiAHqjwB0P3CAmMY1iMjRCn0YR6Y/JY4fuvaIvz4K@VCK7gesao4gSeTewqEwM3yLydjhIPOrHkUwiasZO4EfEDkLSp3FMQ0IvRzR0qG9SSTKNmHSICbyS6xMtYk32qPVtUiI71E78AdU2VqU4SMwhGYUOCJZAtWOTcZAQA21PFVaJZ5xREiUhxVF4geXYYwIW1EZjEgUkHoK@eEjHwEKJ45tuYlELGggkruOfSdQcBkTzibzUkME0zluAriDUCqJJ6CpCo8DzqGY7l4iTRuN4GPirU9CH24/vfbh9b7/34PHe/rN2Q9r526f7x215SbkwiWa2cOiqLMGomeOIa/iDxBhQRb2SFpg@uUSWJqXUyFKjSpaYJIgQBExOaZ8kvu/4A8IGc2tFWuhDyEEPG0gnSOJREgtaMeaPQ3rewRCZMbVSMdNwzXelBQjAIjG9EeFiSIokt27NRwDXJjralxa43J@FAdjGqWrkPr20Em/UBOzlpUVS42xHWpjyGnhLmfJBpaGq2ag1cvrzJQVziwtRT3@OMWZO6KQpdI1JNIzjUdTU9YETD5N@zQw8/Wk4fhAf@pAMVI/DsRMHaZtS3TMiSGH9IjRGkMQRSEgDRGScKDKRmQmsLeW4PUBYnkW0MPFZeheRx5ghQBAmML30YBTrLGf4sxb2Zxg6rQ6QpwnGOGwnGrIHZvo0/S5QMypTi01T7zu@Dt/zjdmFqW4GhpuxiH7WmKfgI8cD@nPHy6YwtGsxpEBHt@i57ieuS1Y6txqYGxgXgS7KOOy/xMXinGpo7gDtuyRBBjS5XC0owpgKEFnTp4BFwdkasp6OqZ9BmC/sft@ZGVK@8kxxMRZoc3s@JrHhuDijKqsbRf4DSJe9w2Oye/iI2I5LCwHjq0eR@F7gzonpIHBZWKPQTNvznP@hXxzgaMw6RNOi2GpvrEMjEQRvH@PdGc/c1bzYdnR8gIQU@HYJa98jIQOvzcjoh4bj24l5lolIAXlrhulp@D2DjsO3DJrJ1GzXmNQ3NEDfDrbuG0If0bYnGGHplPnXjND7RnRGXZdNYhDFOjNErxj/qzns1AteOtPhZ0D@nBd2obKyA5AjA3dWP5rUrz0r4mZneqWCE61SwYlmwlc6wczRKJ9YolNk3PeC2PEDzzEDHxe8y1EQxuTx4d5@72j76f32qawnUai7Tl/3QWQPtuHEpdGpjBIRko0vEzPRqb2cNfaM@e5sju8sHhZrXljyLHnvDH9H5my7jjm5ThsI0WE7oeEopPCct1r/NDGsH2LHL3K@GZkbG6mcjQ0ddngaj/E5Rzca90N0Z3wzMqOx1w9g4KQ4cb3AD8Te1bfxr0YvOeu8LYBRsyoPqCa2Quj/@dZGKdesrbB70yiVxHt6DPUijfWQutSIqIDO7sp0FP8gW0aTjpNYvWGT8qnfgiTpsBKvU87qQyzGsDo2sUQJRtRXykhRVmshNSxFbTJ@xcSCNwgtxVQ77dUVLLR5r9VYuYs9E6ZWDDLKrc6tpTJ1oSi3y7dKV5zqerNcpb7VLpehTEotaunMlpaOdp36p/4RK42a2Cyz2lzUSoJBPvVPoDwiDhRWrCha7J48fXDYRfrH9DKG8j@6gArfS@DIgNbQS5NCQYjlGqtOO43V1R/z5nJjVW/Um7xTuV1XVV661lBYqZRWg9iTJawH0dSPI5BWjvQXOoGPXi74lhnSzAo6rNthKdRLpdzTvJZ/8@Y8cCyiL2tXmkZKwyeLz7QtcvRi@MtfPtvaqu@R@p48POfA50NSeXaHyI8WHxHqQgAeHe6S48M9SsODpesKfE6WdV0/lYheISX4gs2B@oYH6bOkYPjwSEHAvYGpLy3pkKYqK6Q3m61Wef/woExKnc6p1KiAEDLzOTyV9GXyo8HAvOc5H/3o@fPNIAhkN7gnb/64Xf/geLHRAECLlYNSyaI2rgDHWO3xj65vSyXHBgTp9cyRm0T4p@uuRGxF3Syq0nUHSPl5qGXCJuoEHV03C1IrFZCr61SCFIuL5oJqSCzHzkCntVzr4c5Pdnu9onEaPXdik77sH6aMEhzaHB8OODyYyrGqL@sC5HhsbwGDasyoTaikaxehE1N9eVnfvNaXr1tSh5BzaWNjg/C/vImt81ZHOicEXJQXDNX0c3e8qp0zAaUX985nArBVlXfkHuwiwLElAeC8ddKTu4XSsJOJqm61kKJTahWLog55cb50r15voA2MTL67odGBn9h0Rya92aBzc7jEEgcVeMKncu8cDoAgst6AkZF3flqdBtDV7y2dc8LSVnXis1UqSLaM5KdyjzHkHG/9FAcS@07OCryL5xN6vkfS5KcgdUSPwfkTO8LkALZKIDuEFcEKLuAEfxGwjkttXJ4oGUMNFFyQZEQGUIv7nGouENkAEg8BxDqhMxjGTKKgL/Kydt9NKFc1JYc1Curfg/odlr@XkIwvl8hG8mfbjj4AW@a6a76Av8RzUm2cx73GnriYXl13b/7hn/7vm397/T@uEZihMdx9/V83n3/1Ovu5@fu/u/n037/9PTz@@AU8ctjNp78ByK//5ebzb24@/S17/ubm1/@KbYb/7lfYFL@MOe9990mhJ2Cvv/zjF6@/zLrf/mEOI6P7epLru0@R@msQydROihEkn4Axn3@VEnz3q9dfCxLoffv7vP3dJ9AGQvY70WQCgPgPTGEK57CvcfCff/P6y9f/y7YprYVflU63lTYrrcKz0wFMSyAqtY4Gv5pWa7U0/NQqKYJ3O1qKB9JOR8k/Kv6oV9fZL@@lmAx3oign3ZNuStNVocuR7BuwiAYEgzPRCAAOoGFUSKsK6iuiXffasipvKotqO6K/2MTt42OXxqS/CAi5PUri4zhcUmR5UY58KNVj42jgGzsVWa1UHN@JZdelZ5FxX5GvNEnXfRrKt7eeuLePX915uPr8gXataSpm55@@@O3vnJeBR7Fx889f/umLf/zv4nkI@l/dfPafN5/97uaz/9iqnhnyerqg@R/Kb@ww8MgrOBkRvrMtS2KHw8Jh7bZkt13D61sG8ZusFPSr5bCflYKS1e6X8fx5emnb@Feu2Eq5xgppKG7KaqVfzlG8Xa69DGArtZUDFavMA9i@T3iBWS3zggga/EYCGsXLynJXlcy2GXhQHUZR0H@pbFT39g8ebj/d36tqj7af9X628@DpMcJ6j/Yf9R7uf7T/sFpXeVGm8BHV@mu3qY/6FLOWylIstWLWbChGhopa7Ze3dBiiRRkVjDWKQ2eklNtlVX1TInuHx5rrnFFyub5GPIiVZ7iEeolrxHinPHUhDTUaXuVmt9cXQXgWkSENaRXL1gsHTiEIw2IbnOqi@Cp4PwzxmrSfDCIuBGitgEZ@mYsQEvDCGYq5vtF3x8TH0jYOoMiNoY4BjvxSmqGG1B2BwngoKFBBPHQiYvRhhAa7360SOKsTj6ZX0Cb6HypuEthsRYcvbyzKagD6XIA5NCBdYU@U0vSJxpHEcotdHAeBG4kEIyMjjB3DlSRmSeF8wTML9BO7KS3AqAah4ZE2sdNk8@BMDsV@m5w8BlO6y2t37qyuCejJyp21JvxVwAxF8KpdoBVtyaJu1pZCOnDw3jQCgqvyg6Nyk9QvoVyokvLxg0Jn9xnr1OsHB1VpobyHXdSNdEd5e@9B2gai7ZSHSdgpsOykLNeS7RoDrnz3AIAHBpyOgOKw2Hle7BwXO0dZ51qSsK6lYRiEihcNVOY5zHZb3n/y5PBJk1wB@Bq@sjEvhteyKi1AhOCw68RKQ@VC4Ajaw0D08NijoCRsgJHCw5mAE/RYt8su3BkJZAAOqynsKEOFZCYxplfi80LbEkLKoHhKDqm0SQOhcRL6TN6UORd4YERz3ACMmbJSWhg686BCnALYVousq6RC3ECSnuzfO8YEwijx@GL42HOHPSGsPFI8FXhwu8h3f/vhAfJepTFWuBAWB7VKSmT7IaB2OWp3ErX7ME0fhavLUXuI2uGonUnUDqJYogldT8NEqLqPTEe5qgyzixiWxEJThtlDzN6DXFGG2bkviUSCxTBwz9kNWeitM6@HXhXAAxj5BLKxhm7GhSly/Cg2fJMqSAorCXIBG3CkbjsJvS4L/ASMDrpZoISWOVagIhDI2vMivbN9vI8hPUkjCPGqkrS3l/aOJnBHRVwKLdCmEjDLYRnspTnL7T8@4dbACXOdfEDWu8w8NlVSOGyd3AUcAkTMWZysTVaZi/jQmUBwUJUUNUkLeGOCZLhvgaA6NHHDRC/C4ozDRi6kQMn5rEK/zkzJxI9onBGhAAc2gJCasZiZxDBN2AlxggqVlfaU0NSWW2AMbOS2LUkLxUHVM1s87K6xbjrKqek8PdiFbLgZB@riSYHIgp4GI0tnOLd1Oi9UcksYOaMpU2REEYUNKRW78i6p3Oq3Sk1XrHUFQL0g7IFTMWun5keGA/Zk5FI@U@igSoZwTGFTLKUAhGXEBs94mAOAUbm7kbToAUYGKcc2reL4ivgPUnSKFcLztV3o7XIlDJ0mEQsPyyNbxr2Yr@yYUGnuxCD@KhfSrK9csk2maAN3UjTppCpD/cWuClzrXZ6KUkSVKGxk6Z6AfMI1atF1BQZGzyl58BlpSjnrP7ADfOMMYNNbZ8ry7ZWLfK/0SJdREaaJifiDIpVN/UKYZkOUjYvttXOTg@23MxjwUEMYBKzCHALLFZD/9dJoejsXCTXh1/fJqGyTmufWQgBBMI/gpF@m0fns4t6ZwRdm59yEgbHMwTCfAnboiJGKpErFizGmXdIBJXftZg7Q2qla4b8UU5QHRr5boD1P5FuF5rmfyxSEQkTqrAlysOJ76FMODGjYe2mavWgI5wkFzriWg0cXzunOqxHY/uhmDsJ27hsH/3MuZDTJnOoUyIuqHTjqNdZ6q8GIFSZRaDYg56J4foWEaMBko@TLAEJVjl2Zwk7sNziiKHFRNhO0jF8rxRoaFE9lLOcAVnbIOMETRreoY5JXJYvMbmDJOJ5zjgJ/cfyXQcgrQ2Cvoj3TA19n48Z1nlEMREslL3gbWFSxKI7gxJ3OkubE0eD4iNnA3YU9lWi4RWfTvUhYnZ5xqfhgJMrHib20IBQsnT3eoEhUjqvW2/Dp5OQ0s4bPkq9Is7uhyCg4r7G5h/@3DZNR/JYcLuAxe1dYwZWd4/i2NIeM1Ut4Dudi15XiaUIVpwmUz2mQp77BVmvxvlSblMusYLKsMI8JnC5YsXgxdFzKhPHyzacXQGQOQ4UpQyaVEXJ@ftzjhSIjBelLcCjpw5ZwxhBCKxACHiH8RMvB6T8Ni7u12FTKH/qOB6UCXliwl@jilQbJXlyDnQXbbE8pF1b0tzILHwJf1smYJRa4RLxLyA6F4GirSfhtWVPsStzPg6yNOTw9xavIulpvFmYXB935fmkv5kkrgcm366CpfnnnAF9HhOH0qRtcoNS19VyqmHxzDVrbaM4sdwxxdy0XML0UFxcc2PoLqwkXalrNPOPxyJl2TH40FFeN0GmSQgWWl3U46VTBZdH35tJyLhzzLFvuCcGSkQejdyoRC4wq4ckMTlT0spoe0KifeDQ0YPLiAQ@nN3vllB1qCtmDpK@ckRIa/oAqGLkqBG4NnutwSDopekjwiZGnPTGirMss7rLyppikJ@JEw4xkF2P8Hk4pEDHbYemcmNEMP29BisMxKhkavuWyk/GEOtaBihD/4w6z6G/oeB8nWmHGyYl/5uM/YAp8TT7doJ/VfkK@or6ZvjDM7gpNfvhOLwpr0ciF9bB86sNUxXs/xJ9osFyXgCNKPH7xSfmbsPydEEdcZlKINGzl@C6BxF/LAMHyduQ01yvN5kqlefvusuZVN2UpWxtlmUe/ak6GnbOzEqHN33nQVld4FrhIiXqbomSGMbkq1CdOM9IYsXvidDl9vhrikhp9sHGnsrqS3mnzVzW5KLkqXi79fw)

Next answer must not exceed 2821 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020  .>  #^Gv        
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22           @,"B"_"
00000230: 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d  Tr",,@.   v<[_"]
00000240: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c  Befunge-93">,,,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,,,@<.   >#<"
00000260: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
00000270: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
00000280: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
000002a0: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
000002b0: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
000002c0: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
000002f0: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000300: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000310: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030  gnuferdauQ"_1000
00000320: 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  00G$v.          
00000330: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000340: 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665      ,,"79-egnufe
00000350: 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030 3030 3030 4724  tniuQ"_1000000G$
00000360: 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a  !v@,,,,,,,,,,,,.
00000370: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000380: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000390: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2237 392d              "79-
000003a0: 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553 225f 2253 6578  egnufetpeS"_"Sex
000003b0: 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722 2340 2c2c 2c2c  efunge-97"#@,,,,
000003c0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c0a 2072 6564  ,,,,,,,,@#,. red
000003d0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
000003e0: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
000003f0: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000400: 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  ow up green down
00000410: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
00000420: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
00000430: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
00000440: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
00000450: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77  een down red dow
00000460: 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  n one yellow dow
00000470: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000480: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000490: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
000004a0: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
000004b0: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
000004c0: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
000004d0: 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77  left one red dow
000004e0: 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  n three yellow d
000004f0: 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  own yellow down 
00000500: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000510: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20  down red up two 
00000520: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  green down yello
00000530: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
00000540: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075   blue left red u
00000550: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
00000560: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
00000570: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000580: 7565 206c 6566 740a 2e79 2020 2020 2020  ue left..y      
00000590: 2020 2020 2e20 2020 2020 2a2f 2f2f 7b7d      .     *///{}
000005a0: 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372 6168  ]........laocrah
000005b0: 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  C...............
000005c0: e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2 86a8  ................
000005d0: c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3 9fe2  ................
000005e0: 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690 e289  ................
000005f0: a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286 92e2  ................
00000600: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000610: e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000620: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1  ................
00000630: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692 e286  ................
00000640: a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000650: 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000660: c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82 e286  ................
00000670: a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000680: e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c 82e2  ................
00000690: 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
000006a0: c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80  ................
000006b0: c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2 96b2  ................
000006c0: e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2 a1ce  ................
000006d0: b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
000006e0: b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2 bb2b  ...............+
000006f0: 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d  +++[-<+++++>]<[-
00000700: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  <++++++<+++++<++
00000710: 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  +++>>>]<<<++++++
00000720: 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d  +.>-.>---.<<----
00000730: 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d  -.++++++++.-----
00000740: 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e  .>--.>---.<+.>>>
00000750: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829  ((((((((((()()()
00000760: 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b  ){}){}){}){}()){
00000770: 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29  })((()()()()){})
00000780: 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d  {})[(([][]){}){}
00000790: 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28  ()])([]()){})[](
000007a0: 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b 5d28  ))(([[][]()]([](
000007b0: 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d  )((((([][][])){}
000007c0: 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28 2929  {})[]){})))[]())
000007d0: 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129 3d73  ({ -}_=")";(!)=s
000007e0: 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d  eq;main|let b!_=
000007f0: 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221 2273  ""=putStr$(""!"s
00000800: 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229 2b2b  nrettaPgnaB+")++
00000810: 696e 6974 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 2822 7b2d  init"lleksaH("{-
00000820: 0a2f 2f6e 6572 2234 4052 6c34 537a 354c  .//ner"4@Rl4Sz5L
00000830: 335a 492d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac  3ZI-}--)*///....
00000840: 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad  ijome...........
00000850: 456d 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2  Emotinomicon....
00000860: e28f aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839  .........@,ka"89
00000870: 2d65 676e 7566 656e 5522                 -egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 3):

## 42. V, 3354 bytes

**Note:** This language has nothing to do with [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) or the golfing language [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) based on it!

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///op\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
.L    . .         *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>]((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHT-"NUb4`BJJndO-}--)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*//∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijzaeeeaeeaewuuuweeeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbcttIds/CL@xLC9QYgEgQomTLEk1ydbc9sS2t5bEdUzQHBJokJBDg4kJJ1mhrKls1la1KZab2YSrJQ6amKknlsnnYrZ2HrUxevO8z/6Af2P0D55zuxoUX2Z7ZwCbYfe59@nT3OSDUMcP@mzcFsmnbxCS0Z8Y9z3xAIh96Q98977l@RCIaRqRvBh4NQ9I5J48cuvOKHp/4HalAtn3XNYchJfK2b1OZmJ5N5M2gFw@oF4UyCakVOb4Xkq4fkA6NIhoQejakgUM9i0qSZUakQSzglVyP6CFrslu50yUFskW7sdej@vqKFPmx1SfDwAHBEqh2uuTcj4mJticKS2RgnlASxgHFUQx82@meE7CgPDwnoU@iPuiL@vQcWChxPMuNbWpDA4HEdbwTiVp9n@gekRcqMpjGeXPQZYTafjgOXUFo6A8GVO86Z@O4m4h7Wh6akdWXpOF51Pe9ldnEdwMzDKtSFBDdssnpsxGpMd8gXpIebD66@9Hm3d32/Uc7u8/rFWnrr5/sHtblBfXUAgZGqskSeIw5nbim14vNHlW1C2mOqZALZGFcSpksVEpkgUmC2YXJlhPax7HnOV6PMEfcWJbmOhAuoIc5oeHH0TCOpDmwdVN/QUz9FakRDoTh8obuWkIYc8RFpVS6lD8J6KiBMWBF1E50zcLpnivNwSzPE2swzCSSBE9u3LgWB7x3cE49aY5reBb4MBROWCb36JkdD4ZVwJ6d2SQZS9eR5iacDM5VJ1xWrGha6iSdHH28oGIYcyHa0ccYTsxnjSRaLzFe@1E0DKuG0XOiftwpW/7AeBKc34/2PYg7akTBuRP5SZtSY2CGsFqM08AcwnoJpWQ2ibwjE9ke2EQPYo@tFTmHPMS4AoIghrVq@MPIYJHG7@WgM8XQqDWAPAlLxtF1wj674bKZpN8GakZl6ZFlGR3HM@B7tjHbsG9YvummLKKfNmYpeOoMgH7kDNL9ANrlCOa5Ydh0ZHix65Llxo0KBgB6XqDzMvY7H@LOM6I6mttD@86I3zkWQIvL1f08jKkAkWVjApgXnG5Ia8mYOimE@aLb6ThTQ8q2sQkuxgJtbs8nJDIdF5dYcWU9z78HAbGzf0i29x@SruPS3ITxrShPfNd3Z8xpz3fZtIaBlbRnOf8jLz/A4TnrEF0PI7u@vgaNWBBcP8bbU565rQ@irmPgDSQkwOslrL5DQgpenZLRCUzH68bWSSoiAWStKaYnwTsGHQXXDJrJ1LuuOa6vb4K@LWzdM4U@om@OMcJeKvOvKaH3zPCEui5bxCCKdaaIXjH@VzPY6cA/diannwH5fda0C5XFLYAcmHhMe@G4fv15Hje90otFXGjFIi40C76SBWYNh9nCEp084@7AjxzPHziW74EE2MD9ICKP9nd22webT@7Vj2QjDgPDdTqGByLbcKbHLg2PZJSIkHR8qZixTvl42tgT5ruTGb6z@bTYs6Yli5L3jvC3RM6m61jj@7SJEAMODBoMAwr3Wbv1z2LT/jF2/Dzjm5K5vp7IWV834Min0TneZ@hG436M7pRvSmZ4Puj4MHCSX7gD3/PF2dXp4qdMzzjrrCOAUbOUEajGjkLo/3Brw4Rr2lY4n2mYSOI9I4Lkk0ZGQF1qhlRAp09lOox@lC3D6xy3h1me79iJsK7op40pDpZcjkVcDyH8PivWTHfYn7mTCgQpOx6mU5Bsjm0Fm4@ebh4CV7Y6LdMbmSFbwLPWo2cOwH1QXiSgRGWCMGwnBANix7UzWMo1tQGOHNw8j82RCWepC6OD3Lsv9gnAEXabSjuABbMJkanDYcy/GdtI78KeYhpPy/0QdzX2PSMWcxsmI@FKJJYHdoly5NVgaTdYpt5Q0loAc2oskCxMHf0h9VQFKRStHFDTVrUq41ctrHn8wFYtrVFfWcZai/dqleXb2LNgQ4xAhlJr3FhQqAt1WVe5UbjgVJd3lBL17LqiQPqaWFQzmC01A@068o68A5ayVrGpsPJM5LCCQT7ympC2EgcSXpaszreaT@7vt5D@ET2LoAIMT6HIG8RQNaI19MyikKtjGs2KjEZlZeWnvLlYWTEqS1XeKd5c0jRegZRRWKGQZOnYkyXM09HUT0KQpoTGS4PAZSg53zJDqmmijaUbzIdRKGSe5uXcmzcjXCDGon6h66TQfzz/XN8gBy/7v/jF842NpR2ytCP3Rxz4ok@Kz28R@eH8Q0JdmICH@9vkcH@H0mBv4bIIV3PRMCBIjiRiFEkBvuBQpxicUNaoOIFYVxJwsG8ZCwsGbC8aK3TuVGs1ZXd/TyGFRuNIqhRBDJm69o8kY5H8pNez7g6cpz958eKO7/uy69@V7/y0vvTB4XylAoAaS@Olgk27uHMfYpbOL8PYlApOFxCk3baGbhzixzBciXRV7U5elWE4QMqL4poFyY/jNwzDykktFkGuYVAJgizKmwuqIbScbgo6Kmda97c@3G6388bpsAIji37Y2U8YJajcHQ8qVT6d6qFmLBoC5AxYTgAGlZlRd6ACKp8GTkSNxUXjzqWxeFmTGoSMTp/BxW7PTrFz@sMbz06zKxWWfKXf@dZ4Zwx@DeQ9Qc9OZwGfpbZdg3p2PYpf0vr6OuGfrImtUa2xBFelgv@lESEQUlliXEqu2@cr@qhGNtDlhZd3R1Mhu1GSt@Q25EvAsyEBYFRrtuVWrghqpMJKS59s1JCmUajlC4AGeTlauAvGoB2MUL69rtOeF3fplkza0wtlxGKAkW4UOCjHEzyR26MCQZFLlVpDIm@9ao0KeuLuwogTFjZKY9dGISfZNuOfyW3GkHFce@UHEnlOxgq886MxPe@QNH7lpA7pIbh/LPsZH8BG4Z2yYepHMkwezOWeXJJj@HjwseATwceHjwMfW641SAA7su2feiQ69VnHpV08Hig5h4PQPyXxkPSggvU41UwgsgEk6gOIdQKn14@YREGf52XtjhtTrmpCDmvk1L8H9Vssfy8hKV8mkY3kB9uOPgBbZrprtoC/yHNsubP440FYGWvhPd/LU7wP/TTdtJwcrnKN/MrbJC69Q@N76E0wleyefuVbU5@UQPiQE1d4r5LxCrIMl@fJkfzg70RRonLG@CpTPD9SnxiqVH6A@0MZ/iUX5j8Xl62rv/@nP337b6//4Jq@FZj97df/dfXl716n/67@7m@uPvv3734Ltz9@BbcMdvXZFwD51b9cffnt1We/Zvcvrn71r9hm@O9/iU3xnzFnve8/zfUE7PXXf/zq9ddp97vfz2BkdN@Mc33/GVJ/AyKZ2nExguRTMObL3yUE3//y9TeCBHrf/TZrf/8ptIGQ/R9rMgFA/HumMIFz2Dc4@C@/ff316/8pNnWWXOo1/Co2WrWkWazl7o0GYGoCUSw3dPiv6@VaTcerXEwQvNvQEzyQAqeaXRr@0y4u0/@8l2BSXFNVm61mK6FpadDlSPYNWEQDgsGZaAQAB9AwKqTVBPUF0S/bdVmT76jzWj2kP7@DOd8nLo1IZx4Qch0KzMMoWFBleV4OvYBGkXnQ88ytoqwVi47nRLLr0pPQvKfKF7pkGPfuPdHlRx91bn689eGHnr2vX@q61tRbtcZR8whuRwbcjKOmAbdaA//xNgOzr@Tf0VHLYCBEY/PoqGy0Qoj2q7/9x8PNp482t//0v1/8@atf/8Y59gcUG1f//PWfv/qH/84/04L@764@/8@rz39z9fl/bJROTHktOai9j0K8TLxoeg1zbcsJk96xI65jOnWluHECBs7jjl@hNBP/n8ZxfMqoUPsJ/4I8WH7TDfwBeeU6HcLz7kVJ5N9Y1qzelLp11xx0bJN4VVaqeiUl6KSlqmTXOwo@1Tw663bxoxS7qlJmj2eg@FK0YkfJULytlI99SPS76p6GVfAeFBdNXgCXFF6wQYM/54ZG/ocz6IpyXWlpklW3/AHUsWHod47V9dLO7t6DzSe7OyX94ebz9rOt@08OEdZ@uPuw/WD36e6D0pLGy0eVj63cWb1JPdSsWuVElmprRavchaKpr2qljrJhwGBtyqhg1GEUOENVqSua9qZAdvYPddc5oeRsbZUMIDwHpkvoIHbNCH8Anfj1FKpJ/N0x/an11A9OQtKnAS1hgX3quC6D4WMBcK@L4kswD0GAv8t14l7IhQCt7dPQU7gIIQF/HYWis2N23HPiYREe@VCOR1BvAUf2CypD9ak7BIVRX1CggqjvhMTswAhN9oNiiZjhCRnQ5PdSC2fCi0Lid1nuA1@Dc/EAAIAeF2D1TVihkIdKSSCF56HEoow/qvLdUIQaGZpB5JiuJDFLck9CeIyBftKtSnMwql5gDkiddJOwG9CBH5wDpPkITGktrt66tbIqoM3lW6tV@BTBDFXwai2gFW3Jpm7algLac/CXtxAILpT7B0qVLJ3B2VciyuH9XGf7OessLe3tlaQ5ZQe7qBvpDrL2zv2kDUSbCQ@TsJVj2UpYLqWua/a48u09AO6ZbogU@/nOi3znMN85SDuXkoT1Nw0CP1AHYU9jnsNo78q7jx/vP66SCwBfwlc65vngUtakOZihMj1zIrWicSE9GrVxItr4gEZFSdgAI4WHUwFN9FirxX64ZSQQATisqrBDgarEiiMMr9jjDwRsIUQBxRNySLFOKgiN4sBj8ibMOcVHW2iO64MxE1ZKc31nFlSIUwFbq5E1jRSJ60vS4927hxhAOEt8fnH62H2L3WFa@UzxUOCT20K@e5sP9pD3IpljlQth86CVSIFsPgDUNkdtj6O2HyTho3J1GWoHUVsctTWO2kIUCzSh60kQC1X3kOkgU5VithHDglhoSjE7iNm5nylKMVv3JBFIsBn67oj9AhMM1pjXg0EJwD0Y@Riysopuxo0pdLwwMj2LqkgKOwlyARtwJG5rBoMWm/gxGO210okSWmZYgYpAIGvPmumtzcNdnNJmMoMwXyWS9HaS3sEY7iCPS6A52kQCRjlsg@0kZrn9h01ujWGQNfIBWWsx89hSSeBwiHIXcAgQMWdxsjpZYS7iQ2cCwUElktckzeGzXSTDcwsELUETj070ImzOOGzkQgqUnK0q9OvUkoy9kEYpEQpw4AAIqBWJlUlMy4KTEBeoUFmsTwhNbLkBxsCR3u1K0lx@UEupLQPsrrJuMsqJ5Tw52Ll0uCkH6uJBgcicngojS1Y4t3UyLjRyQxg5pSlVZIYhhQMpEbv8Nqnc6mulJjvWmgqgth@0wakYtRPrI8UBezx0KV8ptFcifSjo2RJLKABhm5HJIx7WAGA07m4kzXuAkUHIsUMrP748/oMEnWCF8GxvF3pbXAlDJ0HEpofFUVfGs5jv7BhQSexEIP4iE1JdWj5jh0zeBu6kcNxJJYb6i13lu/bbPBUmiBJR2ciSMwH5hGu0vOtyDIyeU/LJZ6QJ5bT/wA7wjdODQ2@NKcuOVy7yvcIj2UbFNI0txB81U@nSz03T9BSl42Jn7czgYOftFAY8VBEGAaswh8B2BeT/f2E0eZyLgBrz6/tEVHpIzXJrbgJBMJ/Bcb9MorPVxb0zhc@tzpkBA2OZgWE@BWzfESMVQZWIF2NMuqQBSm53qxlArydqhf8STF4eGPl2gd1ZIq8VmsV@JlMQChGJs8bIwYp30CccOKFB@9iy2mEf6gkV6m/bwdKFc7qzcgR2Prqpg7Cd@cbBN7OEjCqZkZ0CeV61A6VeZbW94g9ZYhIGVgViLoxmZ0iIBkw6Sr4NIFTj2OUJ7Nh5gyMKYxdlM0GL@LWcz6FB8UTEcg5gZUVGEyuMVl7HOK9G5pndwJJyvOAcOf78@M/8gGeGwF5CeyYHvsbGjfs8o@iJlkZe8jawaGJTHELFnayS6lhpcHjAbODuwp5GdDyi0@WeJyxNrrhEvD8U6ePYWZoTCpZOlzcoEpXjrnUdPlmcnGba8GnyZWn6NBQRBfUaW3v4XlAQD6NrYjiHx@hdZglXWsfxY2kGGcuXsA7nYtfUfDWhiWoC5XMa5FlaZ7u1eNe3ThSFJUy2HWRzAtUFSxZP@45LmTCevnn0FIisfqAyZcikMULOz8s9nigyUpC@AEVJB46EE4YQWoEQ8AjhFS0HJ6835E9rcagoH3nOAFIFfGDB3viOliskfVMaThZsszNFye3o1zILHwJf2kmZJTZxsXjxnRWF4Gi7Svhzs6o4lbife2kbY3hyiZeQdWWpmltdHHTr3dJezpJWAJNvLoGmpbNbe/juPAynQ13/FKWurmVSxeKbadDqenVqu2OI26uZgMmtOL/hwNGf2024UMuuZhGPJWfSsXhpKB46QqdKchlYltbhotMEl03fm0vPuHDM02yZJwRLSu4P36pEbDCahJUZVFT0rJQUaNSLBzQwYfFigYfLm/19BCtqctGDpK@coRqYXo@qOHMlmLhVuK9BkdTMe0jwiZEnPTGitMssbrH0Jh@kTVHRMCPZgzH@HE7NETHbYescW9EMP2tDioJzVNI3PdtllfGYOtaBjBDfDYJV9Ff0fBcXWm7FybF34uFPlTm@Kl9u0E9zPyFfxUev@4HTczzTJelSNZkPO@dkI3vqCmmieD0I7cUXocuQA1onYEofvczeyzeNyurt2zdvGTfXKutr4rzoOmdt9uxZRU6oPNiLfyXienXc58GpEsFHqq6XJbX46xj0YRczDAUcrOITSM7IjixtUSEK8qHIps4ODaCHbRfqz3jAH8JS9nAW2@wNSIc9Wg0p5iUQepBb4GtYKCTdkWUZuyzsStZ4vAnl3LSwzt8M01eWWR85XKRHRVXxigAOCax2NUiRnGqoMx636bRStmxPxo09/GD9VnFlWUMTxJkm/r5i6qlu8kCXjz/3OLccDl04tZQjT2HedzMHTfqGTUneM@wveTK3SHzE6JXN0KmuFavV5WL15u1FfVC6I0uxd2qyTR3wSxXTos6xPwxV7eKy2cKX6EEdCITVgX@xEPKtv0sDSk4N4gMm4KrV5GXEEtkUL0feIOwFcH3PNU9gEMyk@jVRBPgQZjMLFEX8JjIwh6rYXqwqkUlZbrIJTcxuldhYNa25XG29XQekY56tiXcRVf53InyiZah8kbVZXcZcBMhQGqMXIIYFmKa9WV0prd62VlekWvr7L0QIZX9sk8w37H8jyG5gcrCcglpOI@xlRNvPceFlkZpO@ndphH8oQvqTWNyVLOJ3J@B4KfMK0RuzFPa1GeRtJO4NiWpVQ03SdR3fFfqh5meGkkajjuLKREV5/wc)<sup>1</sup>

Next answer must not exceed 4360 bytes.

### Explanation

Both **Brainfuck** and **V** use `[]` for looping and `.` for printing. Once we hit the **Brainfuck** section the active cell of **V** is `0` so wrapping it in `[]` will no-op it - leaving us with:

```
+[- <brainfuck-code> ]
```

This way **Brainfuck** executes its code but **V** ignores it, now we can insert it (just after all the `[]`s of **Brain-flak**) where we need to zero the active cell of **Brainfuck** and make sure **V** executes its code:

```
[-]<>\[ <V-code> /]
```

Where the last `/` makes sure we leave the `[]`s again. Actual code:

```
\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K9NNy80vSfz/P8bGLiZGH0jox0TrAwkbOxCEsMHCYAoGY2Ji9cFCIGkQMyZG7/9/AA)

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 705c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  /op\. /+ #\. bas
00000060: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
00000070: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000080: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000090: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
000000b0: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
000000c0: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
000000d0: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
000000e0: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
000000f0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000100: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000110: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
00000120: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
00000130: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
00000140: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
00000150: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
00000160: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
00000170: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000180: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000190: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
000001a0: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
000001b0: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
000001c0: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
000001d0: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
000001e0: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
000001f0: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000200: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000210: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
00000220: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
00000230: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
00000240: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000250: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
00000260: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
00000270: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000280: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000290: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002a0: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
000002c0: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
000002f0: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000300: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000310: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
00000320: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
00000330: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
00000340: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
00000350: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
00000360: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
00000370: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000380: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000390: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
000003a0: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
000003b0: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
000003c0: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
000003d0: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
000003e0: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
000003f0: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000400: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000410: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
00000420: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
00000430: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
00000440: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
00000450: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000470: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000480: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000490: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
000004a0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
000004b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004c0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004d0: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
000004e0: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
000004f0: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000500: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000510: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000520: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22   <>"v"@. @,"F","
00000530: 7522 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22  u","n","c","t","
00000540: 6f22 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564  o","i","d"<> red
00000550: 2064 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65   down two red le
00000560: 6674 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570  ft one yellow up
00000570: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000580: 6f77 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e  ow up green down
00000590: 2072 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265   red up three re
000005a0: 6420 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c  d right two yell
000005b0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  ow down yellow d
000005c0: 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772  own blue left gr
000005d0: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77  een down red dow
000005e0: 6e20 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  n one yellow dow
000005f0: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000600: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000610: 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65  two red left one
00000620: 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f   yellow up yello
00000630: 7720 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674  w down blue left
00000640: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420   green down red 
00000650: 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77  left one red dow
00000660: 6e20 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064  n three yellow d
00000670: 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  own yellow down 
00000680: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000690: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20  down red up two 
000006a0: 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f  green down yello
000006b0: 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  w up yellow down
000006c0: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075   blue left red u
000006d0: 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768  p three red righ
000006e0: 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  t two yellow dow
000006f0: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000700: 7565 206c 6566 7420 3030 3031 3131 3030  ue left 00011100
00000710: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000720: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
00000730: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000740: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
00000750: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3130 3030 3030  0010000010100000
00000760: 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030  1000001000100000
00000770: 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030  1000100010000000
00000780: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
00000790: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000110000100010
000007a0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030  0010000010001100
000007b0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007c0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007d0: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0010000010001000
000007e0: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0010001000001000
000007f0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130  1000000000100010
00000800: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  0000100010001000
00000810: 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030 3131 3030 3030  0000110000110000
00000820: 3031 3130 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 3030  0110000010011000
00000830: 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  0010001000100010
00000840: 3030 3130 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3031  0010000001001101
00000850: 3131 3030 3030 3030 3131 3030 3131 3131  1100000011001111
00000860: 3030 3031 3130 3031 3130 3030 3030 3030  0001100110000000
00000870: 3130 3031 3131 3030 3131 3131 3030 3030  1001110011110000
00000880: 3131 3031 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  1101110000010000
00000890: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008a0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008b0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
000008c0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3131 3031  0001000110001101
000008d0: 3131 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030 3130  1110001000100010
000008e0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3130 3030 3031  0000100010100001
000008f0: 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0000000100010000
00000900: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000910: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000920: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3030  0001000000010000
00000930: 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130 0a2e 4c20 2020  0000100110..L   
00000940: 202e 202e 2020 2020 2020 2020 202a 2f2f   . .         *//
00000950: 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61 6f63  /{}]........laoc
00000960: 7261 6843 c2ab e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2  rahC............
00000970: b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8 c39f  ................
00000980: e286 a8c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2 8690  ................
00000990: c39f e289 a4e2 96bc e286 92e2 96bc e286  ................
000009a0: 90e2 89a5 e286 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf 83e2  ................
000009b0: 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2 8692  ................
000009c0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8cf 80e2 8692 e286  ................
000009d0: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 a1c3  ................
000009e0: 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4 e286  ................
000009f0: 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000a00: 8692 e286 a8c2 b5e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a10: e286 a8c2 a1cf 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80 e28c  ................
00000a20: 82e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a30: e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296 b2e2  ................
00000a40: 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2 8692  ................
00000a50: e286 a8c2 a1ce b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
00000a60: a1cf 80c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1  ................
00000a70: e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2 96b2  ................
00000a80: c2a1 ceb4 c2a1 cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000a90: b2e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc c2a1  ................
00000aa0: c2bb 2b5b 2d2b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  ..+[-++++[-<++++
00000ab0: 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  +>]<[-<++++++<++
00000ac0: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c  +++<+++++>>>]<<<
00000ad0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
00000ae0: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
00000af0: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
00000b00: 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 5d28 2828 2828 2828 2828  <+.>>>](((((((((
00000b10: 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d  (()()()){}){}){}
00000b20: 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928  ){}()){})((()()(
00000b30: 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b  )()){}){})[(([][
00000b40: 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829  ]){}){}()])([]()
00000b50: 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d  ){})[]())(([[][]
00000b60: 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b  ()]([]()((((([][
00000b70: 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29  ][])){}{})[]){})
00000b80: 2929 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229  ))[]())({ -}_=")
00000b90: 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c  ";(!)=seq;main|l
00000ba0: 6574 2062 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472  et b!_=""=putStr
00000bb0: 2428 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e  $(""!"snrettaPgn
00000bc0: 6142 2b22 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b  aB+")++init"llek
00000bd0: 7361 4828 227b 2d0a 2f2f 4848 542d 224e  saH("{-.//HHT-"N
00000be0: 5562 3460 424a 4a6e 644f 2d7d 2d2d 295b  Ub4`BJJndO-}--)[
00000bf0: 2d5d 3c3e 5c5b 5c3c 3e5c 5c2f 3c3e 5c2f  -]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/
00000c00: 5c5b 2f5c 2f5c 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e 5c5b 2f5c  \[/\/\<><><>\[/\
00000c10: 2f5c 2f3c 3e5c 2f2f 5c2f 3c3e 3c3e 3c3e  /\/<>\//\/<><><>
00000c20: 3c3e 3c3e 5c5c 5d2f 5c2f 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f  <><>\\]/\//\//\/
00000c30: 5c5d 2f5c 2f5c 5c2e 2f5d 732a 2f2f e288  \]/\/\\./]s*//..
00000c40: 9953 4156 4e41 43ef bd90 f09f 92ac 696a  .SAVNAC.......ij
00000c50: 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d  ome...........Em
00000c60: 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f  otinomicon......
00000c70: aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65  .......@,ka"89-e
00000c80: 676e 7566 656e 5573 7373 7373 6161 6161  gnufenUsssssaaaa
00000c90: 6165 6565 6565 6565 6565 6570 6165 6565  aeeeeeeeeeepaeee
00000ca0: 6565 6565 6565 6563 6973 6165 6565 6565  eeeeeeecisaeeeee
00000cb0: 6565 6a69 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565 6565  eejiiiiiiiijeeee
00000cc0: 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6a69  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeji
00000cd0: 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6969 6a65 6565  iiiiiiiiiiiijeee
00000ce0: 6565 6565 656a 6969 6969 6a69 6969 6969  eeeeejiiiijiiiii
00000cf0: 6969 6969 6969 6a7a 6165 6565 6165 6561  iiiiiijzaeeeaeea
00000d00: 6577 7575 7577 6565 6565 6561 6161 616b  ewuuuweeeeeaaaak
00000d10: 6565 6161 6161 7776 7722                 eeaaaawvw"
```

<sup>1: There's a patch for **V** included since TIO's version (or rather [Ørjan Johansen's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen?tab=profile)) treats `!` specially.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## 48. [Brainhype](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainhype), 3890 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M eliF MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///opfzzfzzfzzfzzzfzzfzfzfffzffzzzzzffzfzzzffzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzzzfzfzfzzfzfzfffzzfzfzzzfzffff⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆⠆⡆\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitceJbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  vwWWWWwWWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwww
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>0000110110
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 & I8 H I  d      $$$
a&8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP<
>"gnalokniM"OOOOOOOOO.
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left 0001110000100000100010000010000010100000100000000010001000100000100010000010000010100000100000100010000010001000100000000010001000001000100011000010001000100000100011000010000010001000001000100000100000100000100010000010001000001000100000000010001000001000100010000000110000110000011000001001100000100010001000100010000001001101110000001100111100011001100000001001110011110000110111000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010001100011011110001000100010000010001010000100000001000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000000100110
01 & && &&&     & {}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩+[-++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]>+{}[<<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>->-]<+[<<+.<++++++++++++.>>+.<+++.<--.>+.--------.<++++.>+.>>{}]>](()()()()())<>(()())<>{({}[()])<>({({})({}[()])}{})<>}<>((){[()](<{}((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())>)}{}){{}(<((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())[[]()()()])[])[[]()()()()])[][][][()])((((((()()()){}()){}){}){})[()()])>)}{}({ -}_=")";x--?y
 =y;y="yrruC";(!)=seq;main=let b!_=""in putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++y--?"lleksaH"
--N'Zi(Tji8=@/BmU2)[-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\/\[/\/\<><><>\[/\/\/<>\//\/<><><><><>\\]/\//\//\/\]/\/\\./]s*///∙SAVNACｐ💬ijome💬➡@,ka"89-egnufenUsssssaaaaaeeeeeeeeeepaeeeeeeeeeecisaeeeeeeejiiiiiiiijeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejzaciiiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaceeacewuuuweejiiiijiiiiiiiiiiijeeeaaaakeeaaaawvw⠀⠖⠗⠎⢎⢦⢦⠮"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitceJbO` in ObJective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `eliF MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid
- `ssarG` in Grass
- `kcuhpla` in alphuck
- `SAVNAC` in CANVAS
- `egaugnal sseleman` in nameless language
- `LIve` in evil
- `V` in V
- `elliarb` in braille
- `68xalfniarb` in BrainFlaX86
- `NOOPS` in Spoon
- `yrruC` in Curry
- `gnalokniM` in Minkolang
- `epyhniarb` in Brainhype

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTvbchvHlc@cX8hLa0gTMwQGQ5ASRYIAwrskryQyoixpBUDIYKYBDDEXZC4AIZou16bKtanail158F4e1vbWbmovyVbFFT9sbfZFeY//gT@Q/IH2nO654UJJdjIkZrrPvU@fvpzGoK35vdevF8muYRCN0K4Wdh3tPglcqA1ca9y13IAE1A9IT/Mc6vukPSYPTXrwkp713bawSPZdy9IGPiXivmtQkWiOQcRdrxva1Al8kfhUD0zX8UnH9UibBgH1CD0fUM@kjk4FQdcCUiM68AqWQxSfFdmt2O6QRbJHO6HTpcrW@gze7ltA8MB0@q6lOV0hcEO9RwaeCYoFMM3skLEbEg3bFhtUILbWp8QPPYqttF3D7IwJWFgcjInvkqAH9gQ9OgYWSkxHt0KDGlBAILFAl0D1nksUh4hLJRFM57wZ6BpCDdefhK4j1Hdtmyod83wSdxNxT4oDLdB7gjAYBz3XWZ9PfMfTfL8sBB5RdIOMng5JhfkO8dhm3bUHpkWh@1jTTLB9SD0feoC4HbLnaaZzV9P7RGLFI0t7trlB6E9Cc6hZ4B9ZaLcR0bE0oJHJhUCI3TdM6LoYrLTd0AGfAEYfENUdBCrD9UCsulLs@fNJjblgH@xTTJLz1YZUf6EpL3eV582GfM8JaJd6aqMEpfU1tZsjKxPUgRuTdDzXZmVPs2bpEuxbKNdM0x64XkAOtEArAhVHd3t66jNoGm9IsShcZv1UUw06VJ3QsshabbkkCML93Yd3Pti9c9i69/Dg8Fm1JOz99ePD06q4JI106DjWZbIoQGSzwUEwfEOtSyX5QlhgXS0ukqVJKUWyVCqQJSYJRiEMSjGmfRQ6jul0CQvI5TVhoQ3DGvSwYKy5YTAIA2EBYga8S8DJpEI4EMKOFxRLj4SxgLwoFQqX4oceHdZwrOoBdFakax5OcSxhAUbbDaLbg1QiifFkeflaHPBu49hyhAWu4annQlM4YZHcpedGaA/KgD0/N0jclo4pLEw5GZwrTbksX5LlxEkKafx4ScLphguRGz/GYc18VotnjUscQ70gGPhlVe2aQS9sF2FIqY@98b3g2IHxT9XAG5uBG5cpVW3Nh1lNHXnaAOY1X4h7k4gHIhENG0LMCx02Z4kZ5CmObyDwQphT2ThiI57fi157hqFWqQF5PD0wjo7p99gNp69p@n2gZlS6Eui62jYdFZ7zjdmH@V13NSthiepJYZ6CJ6YN9EPTTuZlKBcD6OepIYEBgJ6P0FkZx@33cYUYUgXN7aJ958Rtn0VAnctV3CyMqQCRRXUKmBWcLBybcZvaCYT5otNumzNNSpebKS7GAmVuz4ck0EwLh1h@fSvLfwQBcXB8SvaPH5AOTMSZDuNLQpb4jmvN6dOua7Fu9T09Ls9z/gdOtoGDMasQRfEDo7q1CYUwIri@jbdnPHNbsYOOqeINJMTA6yVsvEVCAt6YkcHnz1DvJyJiQFqaYXrsvaXRgXdNo5lMBefrCX1s1UqXRR5suxOMMJeK/DEj9K7m96llsUEMolhlhugl4385h53a7pk53f0MyO/zuj1Smd8DyImG2ynHn9SvPMviZkd6Po8DLZ/HgabDIx5g@mCQDqyokmU8tN3AdFzb1F0HJMAEjgvmw@ODw9bJ7uO71Yaohr6nWmZbdUBkCzYgoUX9hogSEZK0LxEzUSmezRrbZ77rz/GdwbvFmNctaZS8c4S/IXJ2LVOfnKc1hKiwYFBv4FG4z5utfxRqxvex4ycp34zMra1YztaWCks@DcZ4n6Mbjfs@uhO@GZn@2G670HCSHbi267jR2tXu4KdIzznrvCWAUbOtO1BNLIVQ/@7W@jHXrK2wPlM/lsRragBJAA1Uj1pU82kEnV2V6SD4XrYMrnPcEe7yXNOIhXWielKY4WCb/ImI6yKE3@fFmmYNenNn0ghBiqaD2ynYbE5MBbsPn@yeAlc6OnXNGWo@G8DzxqOj2eA@SANjUKwyRqiG6YMBoWkZKSzhmpkAhyZOnmfaUIO11ILWQQ7Ui@YJwBF2m9l2AAvuJqKMCRZj/mRsQ6UDc4qmPsFMBGY19pwTi5kJk5HMWy8si2ZdCtX4ObsipumUGK9tmVQns8Qou7MxN3D5lIob1YfHxyenIk/4OIbYISTgbcoScdhN25oTapY1JiPYoM7brT7QPBjJvkHvUNpXfZRRIJB@DzBJOHVc2Ot2jzy3OxELoeeNYxvGnhfuxzYwzLvZMBqNINIg07e1wOwXQ8dU@ia1igZVPxpofd2HSdOg58VeYFupRXsPjrOWJAn99Mpox4i01Fotlm7FyyQeCMz0SW88wE7ERA/ywYtLta40Mfvjc1R00BATYmC8cS@SkoqQqGPO0CG5hlOBZaDGsrpaLsnfMf/CQw8d0wx3QB0phxQ5uehRzZDkMuOXdDyncD1D0uVadX0Nz094rVJau401HRbPAGTkKrXlpRy1fEo6ueXFC051uZ0rUMeo5nKQ6sQWVVRmS0VFuxpOwzlh6U0Zizl25BLlOxGD2HDqkOIQE5IjltjcaNYf3ztuIv1Deh4QzfFH1ONBgNbQc52CRzHlYglprbS@/kNeXCmtq6XVMq/kb67KMs9WiyhscTHO6LAmCpjToakfRv3zQiVwqbmMb5kh5STE8LgFxq66uJh6mh/BvH49xMlUXVEuFIUs9h7deKbskJMXvY8@erazs3pAVg/E3pADn/dI/tktiLUbDwi1zCPy4HifnB4fUOodLV3m4aqvqCqEQufly@SfP@Cvg5@XeGEp82B/L2cqyJBC4br68pOrrz55l3tDIGqeLMIDNqAUJ1JIwSUMIDyLItDBrq4uLamwFMosKd8uVyq5w@OjHFms1RpCKQ/NIDPXcUNQV8gPul39jm0@@cHz59uu64qWe0fc/mF19b3TG6USACos5RQWDdrBXcYpZpT8UtVdYdHsAIK0WvrACn38qKolkI4kb2dVqaoJpPwgraLDRt10a6qqZ6Tm8yBXVakAQR5kzQXVENpmJwE1iqnW473391utrHEKrBaBTt9vH8eMAsxTpiPJFzycpFNZXVEjUHTgAwYVmVHbkK0XR54ZUHVlRd2@VFcuK0KNkOHoKVzs9nSEldF3LzwdpVciLH4kz2xpsjIBvwbyjqCno3nAp4lt16CeXo/il7C1tUX4Jy1iaViprcJVKuG/MCQEQipN4grxdXu8rgwrZAddvvjiznAmZHcK4p7Ygr098OwIABhW6i2xmUnYa4mwwuqHOxWkqS1WsslqjbwYLt0BY9AORije3lJo1wk7dE8krdmBMmQxwEh3Fjkow@M9FlvDRYIiV0uVmkDeeFVqJfTEnaUhJ1zcKUxcO4sZyYYW/khsMYaU49or25DAMVNW4L0xnNDzFkmTV0bqgJ6C@yd26pMN2Fl8q2zo@qEInbdM7m2Su@QeIQZHLC0tCdryZnd5vXuzu/Fo64Rd4Hux62iW23fMB@JxfBUFDIYjsSCG8HHgo8MngI8LHxM@hlipEQ@WFMMdOSQYuaxi0Q6ub5SMYdfnjkg4IF2PUodTzQUiG0CCHoBYxTO7vYBJjOizvKzctkLKVU3JYYWM@negfoPl7yQk4UslspZ8Z9vRB2DLXHfNF/BneY7NFyyAeRSXJkp4z9ayFO9CP0s3KyeDK10jv/Qmiatv0fgOemNMKb0nj2xp5pMQRD7kxCVeK6W8EVmKy/JkSL7zM1YUq5zTvtIMz/fUFzVVWIWsDrfvy/DBa5lcXDavfv5Pf/zdL1/9j6W5uqf19l/919XnX79K/q7@7m@uPvn3P/wGbr//Am4p7OqTzwDys3@9@vx3V5/8gt0/u/rZv2GZ4b/9KRajf8ac1r79OFOLYK@@@v0Xr75Kqn/47RxGRvfNJNe3nyD1NyCSqZ0UE5F8DMZ8/nVM8O1PX30TkUDtD79Jy99@DGUgZP8TRSYAiH/LFMZwDvsGG//571599ep///TFP/w6ewgI9a@vPv3Pq09/dfXpf@TrCts2KxV85GvNSlzMVzL3Wq3WrOUvLusVuDg6X6wp8K8oxUpFwauYjxG8WlNiPJDWlJrSrOSBP1@MBURSahxSrCB9xMzZGBopICZqTUmS4z@5UpOi54UEVklyE0FYluP6JZQrtUtGeYEQqXJxKaUXFwRE8T@vSYmaCFGXpHqz3oxpmjJUOZI9AYtolI93JhoBwAE0jAppZU5dY2ZdgKCKNHn9hcypMyNkRABRUuN19sd4JnVmFdc5MTNUuiDKZasqyuL2uaL8cCyQ6nh7XBX5OcO2dEOu@vQn27gzr1o0IO0bQCxC2jwIg9PAW5JE8YboOx4NAu0EdgR7eVHO58cgSrQs2ve1u6KgKA9zz03p8Zm5Wd1R9@wP1mRI9Su1Rr0Bt4YKN7VRV@FWqeEfLzMwe8R/jUZTZSBEY7HRKKpNH9PBq7/9x9PdJw939//4f5/96Ytf/Mo8c22Khat//mqn0NfEzXi35Hzg46XhRZNrkCnrph/XzszoOqMz19lLTTezF9JoOvuMwjAcRexn0yRw9fkD8pCrLz@@@vLzqy///urLn1/9C/z/Ev@//G/xNX4pTl5aZpvwfGhFiPIiTDc3bgqdqqXZbUMjTpkdYTiFnNdOjjAEo9rO4TcjjfNOBz@5fEfKFdlJCSTlOTnfzqUoXs4Vz1xIwDrSkYynI0eQ9NX5wUghxxN5KPDvyqCQfQkCqtGRX64pC3oV33XwqO@77TNpq3BweHR/9/HhQUF5sPus9XTv3uNThLUeHD5o3T98cni/sCrzYwWJt63Y3rhJHdQs6cVYlmTIeb3YgWS2J8mFdm5HhcYalFFBq/3AMwdSrpqT5deL5OD4VLHMPiXnmxvENh3T1ixC7dDSAnzZZepNGbPD3iFJXqsZuV7fJz3q0QIevIxMy2IwPC4C91oovgD94OFxHWmHXZ8LAVrDpb6T4yIiCfimy8Bz21rbGhMHD2cCl9DzAPJg4EjfhmGoHrUG/OSOU6CCoGf6RGtDCzX2UkKBaH6f2DR@90XHnnACH98jwS0lPOxxdDAEQIcL0HsajEjID4Q4kPyxL7Ao48fdruVHoUYGmheYmiUIzJLMCRmPMdBPOmVhAVrV9TSbVEknDjub2q43Bkj9IZjSXNm4dWt9I4LW125tlOGTBzOkiFduAm1UFgxqJWXBo10Tv733geAid@8kVyar57ClKJDc6b1MZf8Zq6yuHh0VhIXcAVZRN9KdpOWDe3EZiHZjHiZhL8OyF7NcCh1L63Ll@0cAPNIsHymOs5Xn2cpptnKSVC4FAc9FqOe5nmT7XZl5DqO9Ix4@enT8qEwuAHwJj6TNN7xLURYWoIeK9NwMpJLMhXRp0MKOaOHBnYSSsABGRh5OBNTRY80me/mDkUAEYLPKkR05yBb1MMDwwmNwPKgxIiE5UDwlh@SrpITQIPQcJm/KnBEeeaI5lgvGTFkpLPTMedBInATYSoVsyiRPLFcQHh3eOcUAwl7i/Yvdx@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@RxpSz/gM7wDdmFxa9TaYsXV65yHcKj3gajbppYiB@r55Khn6mm2a7KGkXW2vnBgdbb2cw4KFSZBCwRubgd71A/pcLo@nlPAqoCb@@S0Qli9Q8t2Y6EATzHpz0yzQ6HV3cOzP4zOicGzDQljkY5lPA9syopVFQxeKjNsZVUgMltzvlFKBUY7WR/2JMVh4Y@WaBnXkirxWaxn4qMyKMRMTOmiAHK95CH3Ngh3qtM11v@T3IJyTdhYUMUxfOac3bI7D10UochOXUNya@3RnJKJM5u1Mgz6o2IdUrbbTW3QHbmPieXoKY84P5OyREAyZpJZ8GECpz7NoUdmK9wRb5oYWymaAVfKxl99CgeCpiOQewsiSjjhlGM6tjklcmN5jdwJJwPOccGf5s@89dj@8Mgb2A9kw3fJO1G@d5RtGNSjJ5wcvAIkeT4gAy7niUlCdSg9MTZgN3F9ZkouASnQz3LGFhesTF4t1BtH2cWEszQsHS2fQGRaJynLWuw8eDk9PMGj5LvibMroZRREG@xsYevlvohYPgmhjO4DF619iGK8nj@LI0h4ztlzAP52I3pWw2IUfZBMrnNMizusVm6@j3AlWSy7ENk2F4aZ9AdsE2i6Me/vQEhfHtm0NHQKT3PIkpQyaZEXJ@nu7xjSIjBelLkJS0YUnoM0SkFQgBjxCe0XJw/NpLdrWOFpXcB45pw1YBDyzYr3eCtRJJfm0BKwuW2ZqSy8zo1zJHPgS@pJIwC6zjwuhHTiwpBEcbZcLPzcrRqsT93E3KGMPTQ7yArOur5czo4qBbb5f2Yp60RTD55ipoWj2/dYS/g4LmtKnljlDqxmYqNRp8cw3a2CrPTHcMcXsjFTA9FWcnHFj6M7MJF6ob5TTiMeWMKzpPDaNDR6iUSWYHlm7rcNDJEZdB35lLSbmwzbNsqSciloTcHbxRSTTByAJmZuwtt0KcoFEntKmnweDFBA@HN/stHEtqMtGDpC/NgeRpTpdK2HMF6LgNuG9CklTPeijii1oe16IWJVVmcZNtb7JBWo8yGmYkOxjj53BShojZDlPnxIhm@HkTUuCNUUlPcwyLZcYT6lgFdoT4zhiMor@i40McaJkRJ4ZO38FvgDN8ZT7coJ7s/SL5Eh69Hntm13Q0iyRDVWM@bI/JTnrqCtvE6LUxtBd/TFGEPaDeB1N66GX2tqSmljZu3755S725WdrajNaLjnneYmfPEnJC5sFeHi4Qy6niPA9OFQgeqVpOuqnFrx2hDrOYouTAwRKeQHJGtmTJKzmSQz4UWVfW2H7PITDtQv4Z2vwQlrLDWSyzNxRNdrTqU9yXQOjB3gJfz0MhyYwsilhlYVfQJ@MtUs5N86v8jUFlfY3VkcNCelRUjl7dwCaB1ZYMWySz7CuMx6qbzYQtnZNxYvff27qVX1@T0YRoTYt@ozVzqhsf6PL2Z45zi/7AglUr13ByzPtW5CBYVad9w7ok6xn2q8zULQJvMXpl1zfLm/lyeS1fvnl7RbEL26IQOiONTeqAXy1pOjXP3IEvyReX9WalVigqeRFVglAYIfjLJ59P/x3qUTJSiQsYj6uX4peaC2Q3esl6mf9WUDmytL4s9KwBhsIy9DgzsHpNTEGTfejbNGxy0TcktjaQoslGx5M6ksuDTLnO@jhuSbPAmi/L9bVy882KYIfmGHL02qrEf37G@16EZBhZ6@U13J4AGUpj9BGIYQEmy6831gsbt/WNdaGSvNYDQUPZb/jiEIApEX91Cv2FGRakdzJh760aboYLL51UFNK7QwP8/RnpTWNxotKJ25mC45W7kSNKbZ7CnjyHvIXE3QGR9LIvC4qi4Gtd39X81FBSq1VRXJFIKO//AQ)

Next answer must not exceed 5057 bytes.

### Explanation

Brainhype is a brainfuck extension which adds `{}` which checks whether the program between the parentheses will halt with the current tape configuration, if it does it sets the current cell to 0 and else it leaves it unmodified.

The code basically ended up like this:

```
initialize tape for both brainfuck & Brainhype
+{}
   [
    print 'kcufniarb' & make sure the tape ends with ... 255 (0)
   ]
<+
  [
   print 'epyhniarb'
  ]
>
```

Of course always making sure that all the parentheses are balanced for the Flaks. To distinguish I simply used that `{}` is a no-op in regular brainfuck and in Brainhype it will set the current cell to 0 (every empty bf program halts). Also I had to move the Emotinomicon code to the front of the BF code because it started getting stack-overflows -.-

To test the Brainhype code on TIO we can just transpile the `{}` to a `[-]` and reuse the brainfuck interpreter. However I started a [little project](https://github.com/bforte/brainfs) which implements a lot of brainfuck derivatives that also includes Brainhype.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6946 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M eliF MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f6f 7066 7a7a 667a 7a66 7a7a 667a 7a7a  /opfzzfzzfzzfzzz
00000060: 667a 7a66 7a66 7a66 6666 7a66 667a 7a7a  fzzfzfzfffzffzzz
00000070: 7a7a 6666 7a66 7a7a 7a66 667a 667a 7a7a  zzffzfzzzffzfzzz
00000080: 667a 667a 667a 7a66 7a66 7a7a 7a66 7a66  fzfzfzzfzfzzzfzf
00000090: 7a66 7a7a 667a 667a 6666 667a 7a66 7a66  zfzzfzfzfffzzfzf
000000a0: 7a7a 7a66 7a66 6666 66e2 a086 e2a1 86e2  zzzfzffff.......
000000b0: a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1  ................
000000c0: 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086 e2a1 86e2 a086  ................
000000d0: e2a1 865c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173  ...\. /+ #\. bas
000000e0: 656e 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e  ename "$(readlin
000000f0: 6b20 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922  k /proc/$$/exe)"
00000100: 7c72 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e  |rev;:<<'EOF' #>
00000110: 3e5c 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020  >\.1+///        
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20            O\./* 
00000130: 1b67 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22  .ggcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"
00000140: 6c6f 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f  loG";?=0%S!11ooo
00000150: 3c22 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053  <"><>".#define S
00000160: 2243 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369  "C"       //A.#i
00000170: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
00000180: 2f2f 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020  //l. f();       
00000190: 2020 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564       //i.#includ
000001a0: 653c 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465  e<cstdio>//c.#de
000001b0: 6669 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a  fine S"++C" //e.
000001c0: 2069 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020   int///         
000001d0: 220a 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020  ".#endif//      
000001e0: 205c 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a   \..#ifdef __OBJ
000001f0: 435f 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d  C__.#define S"C-
00000200: 6576 6974 6365 4a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469  evitceJbO".#endi
00000210: 660a 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466  f. main(){printf
00000220: 2853 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70  (S)/*/main(){imp
00000230: 6f72 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244  ort std.stdio;"D
00000240: 222e 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d  ".write/**/;}/*}
00000250: 3c0a 3e20 2076 7757 5757 5777 5757 5757  <.>  vwWWWWwWWWW
00000260: 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757 5777  WwvwWWwWWWwvwWWw
00000270: 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776 7757  WWWwvwWWwWWWwvwW
00000280: 5777 5757 5777 7677 5757 7757 5757 7776  WwWWWwvwWWwWWWwv
00000290: 7757 5777 5757 5777 7657 7777 7777 7777  wWWwWWWwvWwwwwww
000002a0: 7777 7777 7757 5757 7757 5757 5757 5777  wwwwwWWWwWWWWWWw
000002b0: 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW
000002c0: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
000002d0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWwWWWWWW
000002e0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWwWWWW
000002f0: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 7757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWwW
00000300: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000310: 5777 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WwWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000320: 5757 5757 5777 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWwwWWWWWWWWW
00000330: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5777 7777 7777  WWWWWWWWWWWwwwww
00000340: 7757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  wWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000350: 5757 5757 5757 7777 7777 7757 5757 5757  WWWWWWwwwwwWWWWW
00000360: 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757 5757  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
00000370: 5777 7777 7777 7777 7777 7777 0a39 3939  Wwwwwwwwwwww.999
00000380: 2039 3939 2039 390a 3939 3920 3939 3920   999 99.999 999 
00000390: 390a 3939 3976 3c3e 3030 3030 3131 3031  9.999v<>00001101
000003a0: 3130 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d  10.v  <>"efunge-
000003b0: 3938 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d  98",,,,,,,,,7y3-
000003c0: 763c 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020  v< @.>  #^Gv    
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22               @,"
000003e0: 4222 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c  B"_"Tr",,@.   v<
000003f0: 5b5f 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e  [_"]Befunge-93">
00000400: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20  ,,,,,,,,,,0|@<. 
00000410: 2020 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936    >#<"Befunge-96
00000420: 223e 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c  "> ^v$G001.v  ,,
00000430: 2c2c 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220  ,,,"79-egnufeB" 
00000440: 5f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  _               
00000450: 2020 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023     v<.>  ,,,,,@#
00000460: 2020 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566        ,"79-egnuf
00000470: 6572 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e  erT"_v# $G0001<>
00000480: 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .               
00000490: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
000004a0: 3e31 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023  >10000G$v.     #
000004b0: 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40  @,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@
000004c0: 2322 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551  #"79-egnuferdauQ
000004d0: 225f 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020  "_100000G$v.    
000004e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000004f0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d            ,,"79-
00000500: 6567 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030  egnufetniuQ"_100
00000510: 3030 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  0000G$!v@,,,,,,,
00000520: 2c2c 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,,,.          
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2020 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553    "79-egnufetpeS
00000560: 225f 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722  "_"Sexefunge-97"
00000570: 2340 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023  #@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
00000580: 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,.              
00000590: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005a0: 203c 3e22 7622 400a 2026 2049 3820 4820   <>"v"@. & I8 H 
000005b0: 4920 2064 2020 2020 2020 2424 240a 6126  I  d      $$$.a&
000005c0: 3867 2633 6734 6736 5239 5050 5050 5050  8g&3g4g6R9PPPPPP
000005d0: 3c0a 3e22 676e 616c 6f6b 6e69 4d22 4f4f  <.>"gnalokniM"OO
000005e0: 4f4f 4f4f 4f4f 4f2e 0a20 402c 2246 222c  OOOOOOO.. @,"F",
000005f0: 2275 222c 226e 222c 2263 222c 2274 222c  "u","n","c","t",
00000600: 226f 222c 2269 222c 2264 223c 3e20 7265  "o","i","d"<> re
00000610: 6420 646f 776e 2074 776f 2072 6564 206c  d down two red l
00000620: 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075  eft one yellow u
00000630: 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c  p green down yel
00000640: 6c6f 7720 7570 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77  low up green dow
00000650: 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074 6872 6565 2072  n red up three r
00000660: 6564 2072 6967 6874 2074 776f 2079 656c  ed right two yel
00000670: 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  low down yellow 
00000680: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067  down blue left g
00000690: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 646f  reen down red do
000006a0: 776e 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f  wn one yellow do
000006b0: 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265  wn blue left gre
000006c0: 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 646f 776e  en down red down
000006d0: 2074 776f 2072 6564 206c 6566 7420 6f6e   two red left on
000006e0: 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2075 7020 7965 6c6c  e yellow up yell
000006f0: 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566  ow down blue lef
00000700: 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564  t green down red
00000710: 206c 6566 7420 6f6e 6520 7265 6420 646f   left one red do
00000720: 776e 2074 6872 6565 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  wn three yellow 
00000730: 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e  down yellow down
00000740: 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067 7265 656e   blue left green
00000750: 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 7570 2074 776f   down red up two
00000760: 2067 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c   green down yell
00000770: 6f77 2075 7020 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  ow up yellow dow
00000780: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 7265 6420  n blue left red 
00000790: 7570 2074 6872 6565 2072 6564 2072 6967  up three red rig
000007a0: 6874 2074 776f 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f  ht two yellow do
000007b0: 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062  wn yellow down b
000007c0: 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2030 3030 3131 3130  lue left 0001110
000007d0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
000007e0: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030 3030  0001000001010000
000007f0: 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100000000010001
00000800: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
00000810: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030 3030  0001000001010000
00000820: 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030  0100000100010000
00000830: 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030  0100010001000000
00000840: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000100000100
00000850: 3031 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100011000010001
00000860: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3130  0001000001000110
00000870: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
00000880: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000100000100
00000890: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0001000001000100
000008a0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3030 3031 3030  0001000100000100
000008b0: 3031 3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031  0100000000010001
000008c0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030  0000010001000100
000008d0: 3030 3030 3031 3130 3030 3031 3130 3030  0000011000011000
000008e0: 3030 3131 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 3030  0011000001001100
000008f0: 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031  0001000100010001
00000900: 3030 3031 3030 3030 3030 3130 3031 3130  0001000000100110
00000910: 3131 3130 3030 3030 3031 3130 3031 3131  1110000001100111
00000920: 3130 3030 3131 3030 3131 3030 3030 3030  1000110011000000
00000930: 3031 3030 3131 3130 3031 3131 3130 3030  0100111001111000
00000940: 3031 3130 3131 3130 3030 3030 3130 3030  0110111000001000
00000950: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
00000960: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
00000970: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
00000980: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3131 3030 3031 3130  0000100011000110
00000990: 3131 3131 3030 3031 3030 3031 3030 3031  1111000100010001
000009a0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3031 3031 3030 3030  0000010001010000
000009b0: 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030 3130 3030  1000000010001000
000009c0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
000009d0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
000009e0: 3030 3030 3130 3030 3030 3030 3130 3030  0000100000001000
000009f0: 3030 3030 3031 3030 3131 300a 3031 2026  00000100110.01 &
00000a00: 2026 2620 2626 2620 2020 2020 2620 7b7d   && &&&     & {}
00000a10: 5de2 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372 6168  ]........laocrah
00000a20: 43c2 abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2  C...............
00000a30: e28c 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2 86a8  ................
00000a40: c2b2 c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3 9fe2  ................
00000a50: 89a4 e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690 e289  ................
00000a60: a5e2 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286 92e2  ................
00000a70: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000a80: e286 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000a90: 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1  ................
00000aa0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692 e286  ................
00000ab0: a8c3 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000ac0: 86a8 c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000ad0: c2a1 cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82 e286  ................
00000ae0: a8c2 a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000af0: e286 a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c 82e2  ................
00000b00: 86a8 c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000b10: c2a1 ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80  ................
00000b20: c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2 96b2  ................
00000b30: e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2 a1ce  ................
00000b40: b4c2 a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000b50: b2c2 a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2 bbf0  ................
00000b60: 9f98 ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f 6ef0  ...Emotinomicon.
00000b70: 9f98 b2e2 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 2b5b 2d2b  ............+[-+
00000b80: 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d  +++[-<+++++>]<[-
00000b90: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  <++++++<+++++<++
00000ba0: 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3e 2b7b 7d5b 3c3c 3c3c  +++>>>]>+{}[<<<<
00000bb0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
00000bc0: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
00000bd0: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
00000be0: 3c2b 2e3e 3e2d 3e2d 5d3c 2b5b 3c3c 2b2e  <+.>>->-]<+[<<+.
00000bf0: 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e3e  <++++++++++++.>>
00000c00: 2b2e 3c2b 2b2b 2e3c 2d2d 2e3e 2b2e 2d2d  +.<+++.<--.>+.--
00000c10: 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3c 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2b2e  ------.<++++.>+.
00000c20: 3e3e 7b7d 5d3e 5d28 2829 2829 2829 2829  >>{}]>](()()()()
00000c30: 2829 293c 3e28 2829 2829 293c 3e7b 287b  ())<>(()())<>{({
00000c40: 7d5b 2829 5d29 3c3e 287b 287b 7d29 287b  }[()])<>({({})({
00000c50: 7d5b 2829 5d29 7d7b 7d29 3c3e 7d3c 3e28  }[()])}{})<>}<>(
00000c60: 2829 7b5b 2829 5d28 3c7b 7d28 2828 2828  (){[()](<{}(((((
00000c70: 2828 2828 2828 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b  (((((()()()){}){
00000c80: 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828  }){}){}()){})(((
00000c90: 2928 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28  )()()()){}){})[(
00000ca0: 285b 5d5b 5d29 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928  ([][]){}){}()])(
00000cb0: 5b5d 2829 297b 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b  []()){})[]())(([
00000cc0: 5b5d 5b5d 2829 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828  [][]()]([]()((((
00000cd0: 285b 5d5b 5d5b 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d  ([][][])){}{})[]
00000ce0: 297b 7d29 2929 5b5d 2829 293e 297d 7b7d  ){})))[]())>)}{}
00000cf0: 297b 7b7d 283c 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  ){{}(<((((((((((
00000d00: 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d  ((((()()()){}){}
00000d10: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829  ){}){}()){})((()
00000d20: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828  ()()()){}){})[((
00000d30: 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b  [][]){}){}()])([
00000d40: 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 5b5b 5d28  ]()){})[]())[[](
00000d50: 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d29 5b5b 5d28 2928  )()()])[])[[]()(
00000d60: 2928 2928 295d 295b 5d5b 5d5b 5d5b 2829  )()()])[][][][()
00000d70: 5d29 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b  ])((((((()()()){
00000d80: 7d28 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2829  }()){}){}){})[()
00000d90: 2829 5d29 3e29 7d7b 7d28 7b20 2d7d 5f3d  ()])>)}{}({ -}_=
00000da0: 2229 223b 782d 2d3f 790a 203d 793b 793d  ")";x--?y. =y;y=
00000db0: 2279 7272 7543 223b 2821 293d 7365 713b  "yrruC";(!)=seq;
00000dc0: 6d61 696e 3d6c 6574 2062 215f 3d22 2269  main=let b!_=""i
00000dd0: 6e20 7075 7453 7472 2428 2222 2122 736e  n putStr$(""!"sn
00000de0: 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142 2b22 292b 2b79  rettaPgnaB+")++y
00000df0: 2d2d 3f22 6c6c 656b 7361 4822 0a2d 2d4e  --?"lleksaH".--N
00000e00: 275a 6928 546a 6938 3d40 2f42 6d55 3229  'Zi(Tji8=@/BmU2)
00000e10: 5b2d 5d3c 3e5c 5b5c 3c3e 5c5c 2f3c 3e5c  [-]<>\[\<>\\/<>\
00000e20: 2f5c 5b2f 5c2f 5c3c 3e3c 3e3c 3e5c 5b2f  /\[/\/\<><><>\[/
00000e30: 5c2f 5c2f 3c3e 5c2f 2f5c 2f3c 3e3c 3e3c  \/\/<>\//\/<><><
00000e40: 3e3c 3e3c 3e5c 5c5d 2f5c 2f2f 5c2f 2f5c  ><><>\\]/\//\//\
00000e50: 2f5c 5d2f 5c2f 5c5c 2e2f 5d73 2a2f 2f2f  /\]/\/\\./]s*///
00000e60: e288 9953 4156 4e41 43ef bd90 f09f 92ac  ...SAVNAC.......
00000e70: 696a 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 402c 6b61  ijome.......@,ka
00000e80: 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665 6e55 7373 7373  "89-egnufenUssss
00000e90: 7361 6161 6161 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  saaaaaeeeeeeeeee
00000ea0: 7061 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6369 7361  paeeeeeeeeeecisa
00000eb0: 6565 6565 6565 656a 6969 6969 6969 6969  eeeeeeejiiiiiiii
00000ec0: 6a65 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565 6565  jeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
00000ed0: 6565 656a 7a61 6369 6969 6969 6969 6969  eeejzaciiiiiiiii
00000ee0: 6969 6969 6a65 6565 6163 6565 6163 6577  iiiijeeeaceeacew
00000ef0: 7575 7577 6565 6a69 6969 696a 6969 6969  uuuweejiiiijiiii
00000f00: 6969 6969 6969 696a 6565 6561 6161 616b  iiiiiiijeeeaaaak
00000f10: 6565 6161 6161 7776 77e2 a080 e2a0 96e2  eeaaaawvw.......
00000f20: a097 e2a0 8ee2 a28e e2a2 a6e2 a2a6 e2a0  ................
00000f30: ae22                                     ."
```

Answer (score 2):

## 32. symbolic brainfuck, 1567 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_"Quintefunge-97"
.l        .       *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//TJrf$8AlzKx5?x?I-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbbhtHls/qX5iXUlNxd4tsNinZskSRjO6yZ2xLYykZryma0@wukm31hdMXibKiQbADBBhgsRnMQ7DYhw0C7C72MvswweRhsHnyvMf/oB/Y@QPvOVXVzebFTpBdSmxW1bnWOafqnCqya0aDt28LZNu2iUlo30z6vvmIxAH0hoF71XeDmMQ0isnADH0aRaR7RZ44dO8VfXkedKUC2Q1c1xxGlMi7gU1lYvo2kbfDfuJRP45kElErdgI/Ir0gJF0axzQkdDSkoUN9i0qSZcakSSyglVyf6BFrske52yMFskN7id@n@saqFAeJNSDD0AHGEoh2euQqSIiJuqcCS8QzzymJkpDiLLzAdnpXBDQoD69IFJB4APLiAb0CEkoc33ITm9rQwEHiOv65RK1BQHSfyEtVGVTjtLnRFRy1g2hydBVHo8DzqN5zRgiThlfxIPBXp0YfbT85/Gj7cL/z8Mne/rNGVdr5m9P9k4a8pF5aRLfqOHVNlmDWzHDENf1@Yvapql1LC0yeXCBLk1zKZKlaIkuME3gIHCanuE8T33f8PmGTubMiLXTB5SCHTaQZJPEwiQWumPMnIb1ooousmNopm@lx3XelBXDAIrG8IeFsSAokd@7MBwDVJhralxY431@EAejGscrkAR3ZiTesAXQ0skmqXM@RFqasBtZSp2xQrGpaNmudnP1yScXY4ky0s1@ij5kRmmkI3WAQDeJ4GNUMo@/Eg6RbtgLPOA2vHsZHPgQDNeLwyomDtE2p4ZkRhLBxGZpDCOIIOKQOIjIuFJnITAXWlsawPQDYnk30MPFZeOeBJxghgBAmsLyMYBgbLGb4sxx2Zwia9SagpwHGKHpONGAPjPRp/F3AZliWHluW0XV8Az7nK7MLS90KTDcjEf2sMU/Ax44H@BeOly1haJdjCIGmYdMLw09cl6w071QxNtAvApzncdR9iZvFBdVR3T7qNyJBNmhxvnqQH2MigGXZmBrMM872kPV0Tt1shNmi1@06M1Ma7zxTVIwE2lyfT0hsOi6uqOLqRp7@AMJl7@iE7B49Jj3HpTmH8d0jj3wYuHN82g9c5tYotNL2PON/5OcnOLxiHaLrUWw3NtahkQiEd8/x/oxl7ute3HMMfACHdPDdHNa@h0M2vDbDoxuajt9LrPOMRTowbs0QnYbfM@k4fMekGU@955qT8gYmyNvB1gNTyCP69gQhbJ0y/5hh@sCMzqnrskUMrFhnBukVo381h5x6wUtn2v1skD/nuV2ILO7AyLGJmdWPJuXrz/Kw2ZVeLOJCKxZxoVnwkS4wazgcLyzRyRPue0Hs@IHnWIGPG95oGIQxeXK0t9853j590DiTjSQKDdfpGj6w7EAaTlwancnIEUey@WVsJjrll7PKnjPbnc@xnc3dYs9zyzhKfnCEvydytl3HmtynTRwxIJ3QcBhSeM7brX@emPaP0eNXY7oZnhsbKZ@NDQMyPI2v8DlHNir3Y2RndDM8oyuvG8DESX7heoEfiNzV7eG7TEecdF4KYNisygMsGWolTMk9opz5dbBjk1VBTSUrobBewQLSwiweDKmvKoihaOWQmraq1Ri9amFNGIS2amnNxuoK1qK8V6@u3MeeBdEXAw@l3ryzpFAX6taecqdwzbFuNpUS9e2GokAlkWpUN5gudQP1OvPP/GNWPdSwqbDyVZQTgkA@81tQQRAHag9WNyy2W6cPj9qI/4SOYqiQo0sogr0EqmrUho4sCjUTVjSsgGtWV1c/5M3l6qpRrdR4p3i3omm8uisjs0IhLZiwJ0tYMqGqn0TATYmMFwaBl6HkbMsUqWU1D5a2sFsYhcLY0rzcffv2InBsYizr17pOCoOni8/0LXL8YvDrXz/b2qrskcqePLjgg88HpPjsHpEfLz4m1AUHPD7aJSdHe5SGB0s3RXi1lg3DOJOIUSQF@ID9k/qmB4G0pKL7sOomYN7AMpaWDIgHjdWam7V6Xdk/OlBIodk8k6pFYEJmXkdnkrFMftLvW4ee8/FPnj/fDIJAdoNDefPDRuWDk8VqFQbqrGKSCjbt4SI5wYKIvwxjWyo4PQCQTscaukmEb8NwJdJTtc28KMNwAJUfGeoW5BknaBqGleNaLAJfw6AShFicVxdEQ2A5vWzorDyWerTz091OJ6@cTi@c2KIvu0cpoQTnGseHMwB3pnqiGcuGGHI8tv2CQmWm1CYUm@XL0ImpsbxsbN4Yyzd1qUnIhbSxsUH4e9zE1kW9KV0QAiYa59RS@rp/tapfMAaFF4cXMw7YKsk7cgc2WqDYkmDgot7qyO1c9dTMWJW26ojRLNTzdUOTvLhYOqxUqqgDQ5Pvb@i07yc9uiOTzqzTuTqcY4EP5WjCU7lzAWckYFmpwszIe1/1ZhXwKodLFxyxsFWaeG0VcpxtM/k5THZqU5XKbsqtLD4x4q9v2rd//4//8@2/vv6zawZWaA52X//n7Rdfv87@bv/ub28/@7fv/giPv3wJj/HY7We/g5Hf/vPtF9/efvZ79vzd7W//BdsM/uY32BT/jHjce/NprifGXn/1ly9ff5V1v/vTHEKG980k1ZvPEPsbYMnETrIRKJ@CMl98nSK8@c3rbwQK9L7747j95lNoAyL7n2gyBoD8JyYwHedj3@Dkv/j29Vev/5vtJXodP4rNdj1tFuu5Z7MJkLoAFMtNHf51vVyv6/gqF1MA7zb1FA6ozaY6fmn4p13fZP@8l0IyWEtVW@1WO8Vpa9DlQPYJUAQDgI0z1jgAFIDDsBBXE9jXRL/pNGRN3lQXtUZEf7WJa/wTl8akuwgAuQGH2ZM4XFJleVGOfCg5YvO475s7RVkrFh3fiWXXpeeR@UCVr3XJME5/GvaW1rfdVz8b3ftw9OFD/UbXNYzOv375@z84LwOPYuP2n77665f/8F/5ug76X99@/h@3n//h9vN/3yqdm/J6ugz8j@S3vTDwyCuo8AjffpYlsQ3h7r52V@o1XNPr2ibxayxf@yUl7Gb5WrIbXQXr6LNRr4dvpdhTlTIrCCADKVqxq4xBvK2UXwaw3/XUAw1LgQPYY1u8CigpPGtBg5@soJG/dFHammQ14GgPKTyK4KCobpT29g8ebZ/u75X0x9vPOr/YeXh6gmOdx/uPO4/2P95/VKpoPHOqfEbl7tpd6qM81SqnvFRbK1rlHmSMgaqVusqWAVO0KcOCuUZx6AxVpaFo2tsCgcOg7jrnlIzW14gHvvJMl1Avcc0Y78amLtYgkeKVVHYLdxmE5xEZ0JCWsLa4dKCawjGsiMCoLrIvgfXDEK97ukk/4kwA1w5o5CucheCAF2eQcbtm170iPtYfcQCVSAzJBijGl2sMNKDuEATGA4GBAuKBExGzCzM02T1VicCZg3g0vUqz0P5QFpEAKjLIavDhXYnaBwZ9zsAamBCusI1KafhEV5HEYotdgAWBG4kAI0MzjB3TlSSmSa4I5JEF8kmvJi3ArPqh6ZEG6aXB5sHZAiqyBmk9AVXay2v37q2uidHWyr21GryLoIYqaLU24Iq2ZFM3a0sh7Tt4/xMBwrXy8FipkcoI8keJKCcPc53dZ6xTqRwclKQFZQ@7KBvxjsftvYdpG5C2UxrGYSdHspOS3Ehwau1z4bsHMHhgQgkLGEf5zvN85yTfOc46N5KExQcNwyBUvaivMcthtPfk/adPj57WyDUM38BHNufF8EbWpAXwEBTtTqxWNc6kT@MOOqKDtamKnLABSgoLZwxaaLF2m10cMhSIAJxWTeihQO1nJTGGV@LzasgWTBQQPMWHFBukiqNxEvqM35Q6l1jVozpuAMpMaSktDJx5o4KdCtB6naxrpEjcQJKe7h@eYAChl7h/0X3sucOe4FbuKR4K3LltpHuw/egAaa9TH6ucCfODViIFsv0IQLsctDsJ2n2Uho/KxY1Bewja4aCdSdAOgligCVmnYSJEPUCi47GoDLKLEBbEQlIG2UPI3sOxoAyy80ASgQSbYeBesJN@6K0zq4deCYb7MPMJYHUNzYwbU@T4UWz6FlURFXYSpAIyoEjN1gq9NnP8xBjttzNHCSlztEBBwJC153l6Z/tkH13aSj0I/iqRtLeX9o4nYMd5WDqaw005YJTDNthJY5brf9Li2sAxYJ18QNbbTD22VNJxSJ3cBHwEkJixOFqDrDIT8akzhmCgEslLkhbwWItomLeAUQWamDDRirA547SRCjGQ83hVoV1nlmTiR1B8ZNMABg4kgJBasViZxLQsyIS4QIXIYmOKaarLHVAGEnmvJ0kL@UlVMl087K6xbjrLqeU8PdmFbLoZBcriQYHAnJwqQ0tXONd1Oi40ckcoOSMpE2RGEYWElLJdeR9XrvU7uaY71jqchPudIOyAUTFqp9ZHBgPyZOhSvlJov0QGTn/AlliKAQDbjE0e8bAGAKJxcyNq3gIMDUKOJa38/PLwD1JwChXMx3u7kNvmQhg4DSLmHhZHPRlzMd/ZMaDS2ImB/fWYSa2yMmJJJq8DN1I0aaQSA/2fTRW49vssFaWAElHZzNKcgHTCNFredDkChs8xufMZaoo5az/QA2zj9CHprTNh4/TKWf6g8Ei3UeGmiYX4ozyVLf2cm2ZdlM2L5dq5wcHy7QwELFQVCgGpUIfAdgXo/39hNJ3ORUBN2PWHRFSWpOaZNedAYMw9OGmXafB4dXHrzMBzq3NuwMBc5kCYTQE6cMRMRVCl7MUc0y5pgpD7vdp4QG@kYoX9UkieHyj5foa9eSzfyXQc@2OeAlGwSI01gQ5afA9@SoEODTsvLasTDeA8ocIZ13bw6MIp3Xk1AsuPbmYgbI9t4@A3gIJHjcypTgE9L9qBo151rbMaDFlhEoVWFWIuiudXSAgGSDZLvg3gqMahK1PQiXyDM4oSF3kzRsv4sZKvoUHwVMRyCiBlh4wWnjDaeRmTtBpZZHoDSUbxnFPk6PPzHwUhrwyBvIT6TE98nc0b93mG0RctjbzgbSDRxKY4hBN3ukpqE0eDk2OmAzcX9jSiY4rOlnsesTS94lL2wVCUjxO5NMcUNJ093iBLFI671rvg6eLkOLOKz6KvSLPZUEQUnNfY2sPvn8JkGL8jhnNwjN4VVnBl5zieluagsXoJz@Gc7bqaP01o4jSB/DkO0lQ22G4tfvfRIIrCCibbDsc@gdMFKxYvB45LGTNevvn0EpCsQagyYUikMUROz497vFBkqMB9CQ4lXUgJ5wwgpAIiwHGEn2j5cPrNTj5bi6SifOQ7HpQKeGHBfgwUr1RJ9gMcyCzYZjlFye3o7yQWNgS6rJMRS8xxifhNFDsUgqHtGuG3ZTWRlbid@1kbY3h6iZeQdLVSy60uPnTv@7m9mMetACrfrYCkyujeAf6sCqbTpW5wiVzX1sdcxeKbq9DaRm1mu2OA@2tjBtNbcX7DgdSf2004U8uujSMej5xpx@JHQ3HVCJ0ayVVg47IOF50mqGz6g6n0MRXOeZZsbAlBkqEHw/cKERuMJuHJDE5UdFRKD2jUTzwamrB48YCHy5v9dI4danLRg6ivnKEamn6fqui5EjhuDZ7rcEhq5S0k6MTM056YUdZlGrdZeZMP0pY40TAl2cUYv4dTc0hMd9g6J1Y0g8/bkOLwCoUMTN922cl4QhzrQEWIX4vCKvoZvdrHhZZbcXLin/vBpZ@nq/HlBv2s9hP8Ve3t9IVhdldo8cN3elFYjoYu7IfKmQ9LFe/9EN7SYbsuAEWUePzik/Jf9PHvth1xmUnB05DK8QtfKTZDmDQwlrcjp7ZerNVWirW795d1r7QpS9neKMvc@yVr0u2cnJUIDf7FtL66wqPARUyUWxMlM8zJ1aA@cWqRzpDdltPm@OPdELfU6IONe8XVlfROm//kjLOSS@JHcv8L)

Next answer must not exceed 2037 bytes.

### Explanation

The only language that created some minor problems was **Charcoal**, but wrapping the code in `«»` and no-opping it should work: However the parser for **symbolic brainfuck** didn't like the `¿` character of the **Charcoal** code, so I changed that conditional statement to a *for*-loop that executes once:

```
Ｆ¹laocrahC« sbf code »
```

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020  .>  #^Gv        
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22           @,"B"_"
00000230: 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d  Tr",,@.   v<[_"]
00000240: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c  Befunge-93">,,,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,,,@<.   >#<"
00000260: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
00000270: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
00000280: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
000002a0: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
000002b0: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
000002c0: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
000002f0: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000300: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000310: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 2251 7569  gnuferdauQ"_"Qui
00000320: 6e74 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722 0a2e 6c20  ntefunge-97"..l 
00000330: 2020 2020 2020 202e 2020 2020 2020 202a         .       *
00000340: 2f2f 2f7b 7d5d e28e 9aef bca6 c2b9 6c61  ///{}]........la
00000350: 6f63 7261 6843 c2ab e296 b2c2 b2c2 b2c2  ocrahC..........
00000360: b2c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8ce b1e2 86a8  ................
00000370: c39f e286 a8c2 b2c2 b2e2 8c82 e286 a8e2  ................
00000380: 8690 c39f e289 a4e2 96bc e286 92e2 96bc  ................
00000390: e286 90e2 89a5 e286 92e2 8c82 e286 a8cf  ................
000003a0: 83e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c3 9fe2  ................
000003b0: 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8cf 80e2 8692  ................
000003c0: e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2  ................
000003d0: a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 ceb4  ................
000003e0: e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
000003f0: 92e2 8692 e286 a8c2 b5e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000400: 8692 e286 a8c2 a1cf 86e2 86a8 ceb5 cf80  ................
00000410: e28c 82e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286 92e2  ................
00000420: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 cf83 e296  ................
00000430: b2e2 8c82 e286 a8c2 a1cf 83c2 b5c2 a1e2  ................
00000440: 8692 e286 a8c2 a1ce b1c2 a1e2 8692 e286  ................
00000450: a8c2 a1cf 80c2 a1e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000460: c2a1 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1cf 83e2  ................
00000470: 96b2 c2a1 ceb4 c2a1 cf86 e296 b2e2 96b2  ................
00000480: e296 b2e2 96b2 c2a1 ceb5 e296 bce2 96bc  ................
00000490: c2a1 c2bb 2b2b 2b2b 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b  ....++++[-<+++++
000004a0: 3e5d 3c5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b  >]<[-<++++++<+++
000004b0: 2b2b 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 3e3e 3e5d 3c3c 3c2b  ++<+++++>>>]<<<+
000004c0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e3e 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c  ++++++.>-.>---.<
000004d0: 3c2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e  <-----.++++++++.
000004e0: 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2e 3e2d 2d2d 2e3c  -----.>--.>---.<
000004f0: 2b2e 3e3e 3e28 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  +.>>>(((((((((((
00000500: 2928 2928 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b  )()()){}){}){}){
00000510: 7d28 2929 7b7d 2928 2828 2928 2928 2928  }()){})((()()()(
00000520: 2929 7b7d 297b 7d29 5b28 285b 5d5b 5d29  )){}){})[(([][])
00000530: 7b7d 297b 7d28 295d 2928 5b5d 2829 297b  {}){}()])([]()){
00000540: 7d29 5b5d 2829 2928 285b 5b5d 5b5d 2829  })[]())(([[][]()
00000550: 5d28 5b5d 2829 2828 2828 285b 5d5b 5d5b  ]([]()((((([][][
00000560: 5d29 297b 7d7b 7d29 5b5d 297b 7d29 2929  ])){}{})[]){})))
00000570: 5b5d 2829 2928 7b20 2d7d 5f3d 2229 223b  []())({ -}_=")";
00000580: 2821 293d 7365 713b 6d61 696e 7c6c 6574  (!)=seq;main|let
00000590: 2062 215f 3d22 223d 7075 7453 7472 2428   b!_=""=putStr$(
000005a0: 2222 2122 736e 7265 7474 6150 676e 6142  ""!"snrettaPgnaB
000005b0: 2b22 292b 2b69 6e69 7422 6c6c 656b 7361  +")++init"lleksa
000005c0: 4828 227b 2d0a 2f2f 544a 7266 2438 416c  H("{-.//TJrf$8Al
000005d0: 7a4b 7835 3f78 3f49 2d7d 2d2d 292a 2f2f  zKx5?x?I-}--)*//
000005e0: 2ff0 9f92 ac69 6a6f 6d65 f09f 92ac e29e  /....ijome......
000005f0: a1f0 9f98 ad45 6d6f 7469 6e6f 6d69 636f  .....Emotinomico
00000600: 6ef0 9f98 b2e2 8faa e28f ace2 8fa9 402c  n.............@,
00000610: 6b61 2238 392d 6567 6e75 6665 6e55 22    ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Answer (score 2):

## 34. stones, 2088 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_1000000G$!v
                                ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#
 red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left
.y          .     *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//ner"4@Rl4Sz5L3ZI-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbbhvJlc/qX8hLqakxu0U2m5RsWaJIRnfbWdtSLM/Ea4lmmt3VZFt9YfoiidYoGGyAAQIsdoI8DBb7sIMBdhd7yT5kkHlY7Dw57zP/oB/Y/IH3nKrqCy/2OJNQUrPq3OucU1WnSt03ouGbNyWybVnEIHRgJAPfeEjiAHqjwB0P3CAmMY1iMjRCn0YR6Y/JY4fuvaIvz4K@VCK7gesao4gSeTewqEwM3yLydjhIPOrHkUwiasZO4EfEDkLSp3FMQ0IvRzR0qG9SSTKNmHSICbyS6xMtYk32qPVtUiI71E78AdU2VqU4SMwhGYUOCJZAtWOTcZAQA21PFVaJZ5xREiUhxVF4geXYYwIW1EZjEgUkHoK@eEjHwEKJ45tuYlELGggkruOfSdQcBkTzibzUkME0zluAriDUCqJJ6CpCo8DzqGY7l4iTRuN4GPirU9CH24/vfbh9b7/34PHe/rN2Q9r526f7x215SbkwiWa2cOiqLMGomeOIa/iDxBhQRb2SFpg@uUSWJqXUyFKjSpaYJIgQBExOaZ8kvu/4A8IGc2tFWuhDyEEPG0gnSOJREgtaMeaPQ3rewRCZMbVSMdNwzXelBQjAIjG9EeFiSIokt27NRwDXJjralxa43J@FAdjGqWrkPr20Em/UBOzlpUVS42xHWpjyGnhLmfJBpaGq2ag1cvrzJQVziwtRT3@OMWZO6KQpdI1JNIzjUdTU9YETD5N@zQw8/Wk4fhAf@pAMVI/DsRMHaZtS3TMiSGH9IjRGkMQRSEgDRGScKDKRmQmsLeW4PUBYnkW0MPFZeheRx5ghQBAmML30YBTrLGf4sxb2Zxg6rQ6QpwnGOGwnGrIHZvo0/S5QMypTi01T7zu@Dt/zjdmFqW4GhpuxiH7WmKfgI8cD@nPHy6YwtGsxpEBHt@i57ieuS1Y6txqYGxgXgS7KOOy/xMXinGpo7gDtuyRBBjS5XC0owpgKEFnTp4BFwdkasp6OqZ9BmC/sft@ZGVK@8kxxMRZoc3s@JrHhuDijKqsbRf4DSJe9w2Oye/iI2I5LCwHjq0eR@F7gzonpIHBZWKPQTNvznP@hXxzgaMw6RNOi2GpvrEMjEQRvH@PdGc/c1bzYdnR8gIQU@HYJa98jIQOvzcjoh4bj24l5lolIAXlrhulp@D2DjsO3DJrJ1GzXmNQ3NEDfDrbuG0If0bYnGGHplPnXjND7RnRGXZdNYhDFOjNErxj/qzns1AteOtPhZ0D@nBd2obKyA5AjA3dWP5rUrz0r4mZneqWCE61SwYlmwlc6wczRKJ9YolNk3PeC2PEDzzEDHxe8y1EQxuTx4d5@72j76f32qawnUai7Tl/3QWQPtuHEpdGpjBIRko0vEzPRqb2cNfaM@e5sju8sHhZrXljyLHnvDH9H5my7jjm5ThsI0WE7oeEopPCct1r/NDGsH2LHL3K@GZkbG6mcjQ0ddngaj/E5Rzca90N0Z3wzMqOx1w9g4KQ4cb3AD8Te1bfxr0YvOeu8LYBRsyoPqCa2Quj/@dZGKdesrbB70yiVxHt6DPUijfWQutSIqIAKVolVBzYpn/otCGmHFWSdclbNYemEtayJBUUwor5SRoqyWgupYSlqk/ErJpanQWgpptppr65gWcx7rcbKXeyZMBFikFFudW4tlakLJbRdvlW64lTXm@Uq9a12uQxFTWpRS2e2tHS069Q/9Y9YIdPEZplV0qKyEQzyqX8CxQxxoAxiJcxi9@Tpg8Mu0j@mlzEU69EF1ONeAgU@WkMvTQrlGxZXrJbsNFZXf8yby41VvVFv8k7ldl1VeaFZQ2GlUlq7YU@WsHpDUz@OQFo50l/oBD56ueBbZkgzK7@wyoaFSy@Vck/zyvvNm/PAsYi@rF1pGikNnyw@07bI0YvhL3/5bGurvkfqe/LwnAOfD0nl2R0iP1p8RKgLAXh0uEuOD/coDQ@WrivwOVnWdf1UInqFlOALlnLqGx7kyZKC4cMDAAH3Bqa@tKRDUqms7N1stlrl/cODMil1OqdSowJCyMzn8FTSl8mPBgPznud89KPnzzeDIJDd4J68@eN2/YPjxUYDAC1WvEkli9o4X4@xNuMfXd@WSo4NCNLrmSM3ifBP112J2Iq6WVSl6w6Q8tNLy4Qtzwk6um4WpFYqIFfXqQQpFhfNBdWQWI6dgU5rudbDnZ/s9npF4zR67sQmfdk/TBklOGI5PhxHeDCVY1Vf1gXI8dhOAAbVmFGbUPfWLkInpvrysr55rS9ft6QOIefSxsYG4X95E1vnrY50Tgi4KN/eq@nn7nhVO2cCSi/unc8EYKsq78g9WPOBY0sCwHnrpCd3C4VcJxNV3WohRafUKpYwHfLifOlevd5AGxiZfHdDowM/semOTHqzQefmcIklDirwhE/l3jkc10BkvQEjI@/8tDoNoKvfWzrnhKWt6sRnq1SQbBnJT@UeY0CWxfPvEY5G5uyx7yD75HI7qW@rJJEQ5q8VXMDp@CJgHZfauJhQMob6IrggyYgMoM71OdVcILIBJB4CiHVCZzCMmURBX@Rl7b6bUK5qSg5rFNS/B/U7LH8vIRlfLpGN5M@2HX0Atsx113wBf4nnpNo4j3yNPXHpu7ru3vzDP/3fN//2@n9cIzBDY7j7@r9uPv/qdfZz8/d/d/Ppv3/7e3j88Qt45LCbT38DkF//y83n39x8@lv2/M3Nr/8V2wz/3a@wKX4Zc9777pNCT8Bef/nHL15/mXW//cMcRkb39STXd58i9dcgkqmdFCNIPgFjPv8qJfjuV6@/FiTQ@/b3efu7T6ANhOx3oskEAPEfmMIUzmFf4@A//@b1l6//l20qWgu/Kp1uK21WWoVnpwOYlkBUah0NfjWt1mpp@KlVUgTvdrQUD6SdjpJ/VPxRr66zX95LMRnuRFFOuifdlKarQpcj2TdgEQ0IBmeiEQAcQMOokFYV1FdEu@61ZVXeVBbVdkR/sYmL/ccujUl/ERBye5TEx3G4pMjyohz5UAbHxtHAN3YqslqpOL4Ty65LzyLjviJfaZKu@zSUb289cW8fv7rzcPX5A@1a01TMzj998dvfOS8Dj2Lj5p@//NMX//jfxbMG9L@6@ew/bz773c1n/7FVPTPk9XRB8z@U39hh4JFXcOogfB9alsR@hNv82m3JbruG17cM4jdZ4eZXy2E/K9wkq90v49nu9NK28a9csZVyjRWpUIqU1Uq/nKN4u1x7GcDGZysHKtaEB7DZnvBysFrm5Qs0@GkfGsWLwHJXlcy2GXhQy0VR0H@pbFT39g8ebj/d36tqj7af9X628@DpMcJ6j/Yf9R7uf7T/sFpXeQml8BHV@mu3qY/6FLOWylIstWLWbCgdhopa7Ze3dBiiRRkVjDWKQ2eklNtlVX1TInuHx5rrnFFyub5GPIiVZ7iEeolrxHhfO3XZCxUVXpNmN8MXQXgWkSENaRWLzAsHKnyEYWkMTnVRfBW8H4Z4BdlPBhEXArRWQCO/zEUICXiZC6VX3@i7Y@JjIRoHUJLGUHUAR37hy1BD6o5AYTwUFKggHjoRMfowQoPdnVYJnIOJR9PrXRP9D/UxCWy2osOXNxZFMAB9LsAcGpCusCVKafpE40hiucUuZYPAjUSCkZERxo7hShKzpHAa4JkF@ondlBZgVIPQ8Eib2GmyeXDehdK8TU4egynd5bU7d1bXBPRk5c5aE/4qYIYieNUu0Iq2ZFE3a0shHTh4JxkBwVX5wVG5SeqXUBdUSfn4QaGz@4x16vWDg6q0UN7DLupGuqO8vfcgbQPRdsrDJOwUWHZSlmvJdo0BV757AMADA84yQHFY7Dwvdo6LnaOscy1JWIXSMAxCxYsGKvMcZrst7z95cvikSa4AfA1f2ZgXw2tZlRYgQnCQdGKloXIhcLzrYSB6eEhRUBI2wEjh4UzACXqs22WX2YwEMgCH1RR2lKFAMpMY0yvxeVlsCSFlUDwlh1TapIHQOAl9Jm/KnAs83qE5bgDGTFkpLQydeVAhTgFsq0XWVVIhbiBJT/bvHWMCYZR4fDF87LnDnhBWHimeCjy4XeS7v/3wAHmv0hgrXAiLg1olJbL9EFC7HLU7idp9mKaPwtXlqD1E7XDUziRqB1Es0YSup2EiVN1HpqNcVYbZRQxLYqEpw@whZu9BrijD7NyXRCLBYhi45@z2KfTWmddDrwrgAYx8AtlYQzfjwhQ5fhQbvkkVJIWVBLmADThSt52EXpcFfgJGB90sUELLHCtQEQhk7XmR3tk@3seQnqQRhHhVSdrbS3tHE7ijIi6FFmhTCZjlsAz20pzl9h@fcGvgPLhOPiDrXWYemyopHLZO7gIOASLmLE7WJqvMRXzoTCA4qEqKmqQFvN9AMty3QFAdmrhhohdhccZhIxdSoOR8VqFfZ6Zk4kc0zohQgAMbQEjNWMxMYpgm7IQ4QYXKSntKaGrLLTAGNnLblqSF4qDqmS0edtdYNx3l1HSeHuxCNtyMA3XxpEBkQU@DkaUznNs6nRcquSWMnNGUKTKiiMKGlIpdeZdUbvVbpaYr1roCoF4Q9sCpmLVT8yPDAXsycimfKXRQJUM4prApllIAwjJig2c8zAHAqNzdSFr0ACODlGObVnF8RfwHKTrFCuH52i70drkShk6TiIWH5ZEt417MV3ZMqDR3YhB/lQtp1lcu2SZTtIE7KZp0UpWh/mJXBa71Lk9FKaJKFDaydE9APuEatei6AgOj55Q8@Iw0pZz1H9gBvnEGsOmtM2X59spFvld6pMuoCNPERPxBkcqmfiFMsyHKxsX22rnJwfbbGQx4qCEMAlZhDoHlCsj/emk0vZ2LhJrw6/tkVLZJzXNrIYAgmEdw0i/T6Hx2ce/M4Auzc27CwFjmYJhPATt0xEhFUqXixRjTLumAkrt2Mwdo7VSt8F@KKcoDI98t0J4n8q1C89zPZQpCISJ11gQ5WPE99CkHBjTsvTTNXjSE84QCZ1zLwaML53Tn1Qhsf3QzB2E7942D/5UWMppkTnUK5EXVDhz1Gmu91WDECpMoNBuQc1E8v0JCNGCyUfJlAKEqx65MYSf2GxxRlLgomwlaxq@VYg0NiqcylnMAKztknOAJo1vUMcmrkkVmN7BkHM85R4G/OP7LIOSVIbBX0Z7pga@zceM6zygGoqWSF7wNLKpYFEdw4k5nSXPiaHB8xGzg7sKeSjTcorPpXiSsTs@4VHwwEuXjxF5aEAqWzh5vUCQqx1Xrbfh0cnKaWcNnyVek2d1QZBSc19jcw/@JhskofksOF/CYvSus4MrOcXxbmkPG6iU8h3Ox60rxNKGK0wTK5zTIU99gq7V4F6lNymVWMFlWmMcEThesWLwYOi5lwnj55tMLIDKHocKUIZPKCDk/P@7xQpGRgvQlOJT0YUs4YwihFQgBjxB@ouXg9F98xd1abCrlD33Hg1IBLyzYC2rxSoNkL4XBzoJttqeUCyv6W5mFD4Ev62TMEgtcIt7TY4dCcLTVJPy2rCl2Je7nQdbGHJ6e4lVkXa03C7OLg@58v7QX86SVwOTbddBUv7xzgK/6wXD61A0uUOraei5VTL65Bq1tNGeWO4a4u5YLmF6KiwsObP2F1YQLNa1mnvF45Ew7Jj8aiqtG6DRJoQLLyzqcdKrgsuh7c2k5F455li33hGDJyIPRO5WIBUaV8GQGJyp6WU0PaNRPPBoaMHnxgIfTm73OyQ41hexB0lfOSAkNf0AVjFwVArcGz3U4JJ0UPST4xMjTnhhR1mUWd1l5U0zSE3GiYUayizF@D6cUiJjtsHROzGiGn7cgxeEYlQwN33LZyXhCHetARYj/H4dZ9Dd0vI8TrTDj5MQ/8/EfMAW@Jp9u0M9qPyFfUd9MXxhmd4UmP3ynF4W1aOTCelg@9WGq4r0f4k80WK5LwBElHr/4pPwtU/6@hSMuMylEGrZy/M@/xF95AMHyduQ01yvN5kqlefvusuZVN2UpWxtlmUe/ak6GnbOzEqHN31DQVld4FrhIiXqbomSGMbkq1CdOM9IYsXvidDl9vhrikhp9sHGnsrqS3mnz1yC5KLkqXtz8fw)

Next answer must not exceed 2714 bytes.

### Explanation

Only **Somme** created needed a fix which required indenting the new code since the fix would have interfered with **Befunge-96**. Other than that it was quite simple code with a weird stack-based language.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020 2020  .>  #^Gv        
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222 5f22           @,"B"_"
00000230: 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f 225d  Tr",,@.   v<[_"]
00000240: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c 2c2c  Befunge-93">,,,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 403c 0a20 2020 3e23 3c22  ,,,,,,@<.   >#<"
00000260: 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e 205e 7624  Befunge-96"> ^v$
00000270: 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c 2c22 3739  G001.v  ,,,,,"79
00000280: 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20 2020 2020  -egnufeB" _     
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2076 3c0a               v<.
000002a0: 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020 2020 2020  >  ,,,,,@#      
000002b0: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 5422 5f76  ,"79-egnuferT"_v
000002c0: 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20 2020 2020  # $G0001<>.     
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31 3030 3030           <>10000
000002f0: 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c 2c2c 2c2c  G$v.     #@,,,,,
00000300: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322 3739 2d65  ,,,,,,,,,@#"79-e
00000310: 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f 3130 3030  gnuferdauQ"_1000
00000320: 3030 3047 2421 760a 2020 2020 2020 2020  000G$!v.        
00000330: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000340: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d 6567          ,,"79-eg
00000350: 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f22 5365 7865  nufetniuQ"_"Sexe
00000360: 6675 6e67 652d 3937 2223 402c 2c2c 2c2c  funge-97"#@,,,,,
00000370: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 230a 2072 6564 2064  ,,,,,,,@#. red d
00000380: 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674  own two red left
00000390: 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2067   one yellow up g
000003a0: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77  reen down yellow
000003b0: 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072   up green down r
000003c0: 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420  ed up three red 
000003d0: 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77  right two yellow
000003e0: 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77   down yellow dow
000003f0: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
00000400: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
00000410: 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  one yellow down 
00000420: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
00000430: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477  down red down tw
00000440: 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079  o red left one y
00000450: 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  ellow up yellow 
00000460: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067  down blue left g
00000470: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 6c65  reen down red le
00000480: 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  ft one red down 
00000490: 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  three yellow dow
000004a0: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
000004b0: 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f  ue left green do
000004c0: 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20 6772  wn red up two gr
000004d0: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  een down yellow 
000004e0: 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062  up yellow down b
000004f0: 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075 7020  lue left red up 
00000500: 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420  three red right 
00000510: 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  two yellow down 
00000520: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565  yellow down blue
00000530: 206c 6566 740a 2e79 2020 2020 2020 2020   left..y        
00000540: 2020 2e20 2020 2020 2a2f 2f2f 7b7d 5de2    .     *///{}].
00000550: 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372 6168 43c2  .......laocrahC.
00000560: abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 e28c  ................
00000570: 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2 86a8 c2b2  ................
00000580: c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3 9fe2 89a4  ................
00000590: e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690 e289 a5e2  ................
000005a0: 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286 92e2 8692  ................
000005b0: e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
000005c0: 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
000005d0: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286  ................
000005e0: 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692 e286 a8c3  ................
000005f0: 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
00000600: c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
00000610: cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82 e286 a8c2  ................
00000620: a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000630: a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
00000640: c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
00000650: ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 c2a1  ................
00000660: e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000670: b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2 a1ce b4c2  ................
00000680: a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2  ................
00000690: a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2 bb2b 2b2b  .............+++
000006a0: 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b  +[-<+++++>]<[-<+
000006b0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b  +++++<+++++<++++
000006c0: 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e  +>>>]<<<+++++++.
000006d0: 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e  >-.>---.<<-----.
000006e0: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e  ++++++++.-----.>
000006f0: 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828  --.>---.<+.>>>((
00000700: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b  ((((((((()()()){
00000710: 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29  }){}){}){}()){})
00000720: 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d  ((()()()()){}){}
00000730: 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829  )[(([][]){}){}()
00000740: 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929  ])([]()){})[]())
00000750: 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b 5d28 2928  (([[][]()]([]()(
00000760: 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d  (((([][][])){}{}
00000770: 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28 2929 287b  )[]){})))[]())({
00000780: 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129 3d73 6571   -}_=")";(!)=seq
00000790: 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d 2222  ;main|let b!_=""
000007a0: 3d70 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221 2273 6e72  =putStr$(""!"snr
000007b0: 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229 2b2b 696e  ettaPgnaB+")++in
000007c0: 6974 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 2822 7b2d 0a2f  it"lleksaH("{-./
000007d0: 2f6e 6572 2234 4052 6c34 537a 354c 335a  /ner"4@Rl4Sz5L3Z
000007e0: 492d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a  I-}--)*///....ij
000007f0: 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d  ome...........Em
00000800: 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f  otinomicon......
00000810: aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65  .......@,ka"89-e
00000820: 676e 7566 656e 5522                      gnufenU"
```

Answer (score 2):

## 36. Functoid, 2248 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///                  O\
/* ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"       //A
#ifdef __cplusplus//l
 f();            //i
#include<cstdio>//c
#define S"++C" //e
 int///         "
#endif//       \.
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<
>  v
999 999 99
999 999 9
999v<>
v  <>"efunge-98",,,,,,,,,7y3-v< @
>  #^Gv                 @,"B"_"Tr",,@
   v<[_"]Befunge-93">,,,,,,,,,,0|@<
   >#<"Befunge-96"> ^v$G001
v  ,,,,,"79-egnufeB" _                  v<
>  ,,,,,@#      ,"79-egnuferT"_v# $G0001<>
                              <>10000G$v
     #@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"79-egnuferdauQ"_100000G$v
                              ,,"79-egnufetniuQ"_1000000G$!v@,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                            "79-egnufetpeS"_"Sexefunge-97"#@,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,
                               <>"v"@
 @,"F","u","n","c","t","o","i","d"<> red down two red left one yellow up green down yellow up green down red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left green down red down one yellow down blue left green down red down two red left one yellow up yellow down blue left green down red left one red down three yellow down yellow down blue left green down red up two green down yellow up yellow down blue left red up three red right two yellow down yellow down blue left
.L              . *///{}]⎚Ｆ¹laocrahC«▲²²²²²⌂↨α↨ß↨²²⌂↨←ß≤▼→▼←≥→⌂↨σ→→→↨ß→→→↨π→→→→→↨¡ß¡→→↨δ→↨ß→→→→↨µ→→→↨¡φ↨επ⌂↨¡ß¡→→→↨¡πσ▲⌂↨¡σµ¡→↨¡α¡→↨¡π¡▲▲▲¡▲▲▲¡σ▲¡δ¡φ▲▲▲▲¡ε▼▼¡»++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++init"lleksaH("{-
//HHLdw6Kj|I*33vMG-}--)*///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash
- `79-egnuferT` in Trefunge-97
- `ecilA` in Alice
- `79-egnuferdauQ` in Quadrefunge-97
- `99` in 99
- `79-egnufetniuQ` in Quintefunge-97
- `kcufniarb cilobmys` in symbolic brainfuck
- `79-egnufexeS` in Sexefunge-97
- `senots` in stones
- `79-egnufetpeS` in Septefunge-97
- `diotcnuF` in Functoid

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rTrbctvIlc/CL@SlBWpMQCQIUrJliSIZ3SVvbEuxPBPvSDQDAg0SFi4MLpRkWampTdVUpWprJ5WHqa192Kmp2t3aS/YhU5mH1M6T8z7@B/3A5g@853Q3QPAi25ksbYLd597nnO4@3ULXiPpv3xbIpmURg9CekfR84yGJA@gNAvey5wYxiWkUk74R@jSKSPeSPHbozkv64izoSgWyHbiuMYgokbcDi8rE8C0ib4a9xKN@HMkkombsBH5E7CAkXRrHNCT0YkBDh/omlSTTiEmLmMAruT7RItZkj0rXJgWyRe3E71FtbVmKg8Tsk0HogGAJVDs2uQwSYqDtqcIy8YwzSqIkpDgKL7Ac@5KABZXBJYkCEvdBX9ynl8BCieObbmJRCxoIJK7jn0nU7AdE84m8UJPBNM6bgy4h1AqicegyQqPA86hmOxeIkwaXcT/wlyegDzcf73@8ub/befB4Z/dZsyZt/e3T3eOmvKCcm0QzGzh0VZZg1MxxxDX8XmL0qKJeSXNMn1wgC@NSKmShViYLTBJECAImp7RPEt93/B5hg7mzJM11IeSghw2kFSTxIIkFrRjzq5AOWxgiM6ZWKmYSrvmuNAcBmCemNyBcDEmR5M6d2QjgWkdH@9Icl/uzMADbOFWFHNALK/EGdcBeXFgkNc52pLkJr4G3lAkflGqqmo1aI6c/X1Awt7gQ9fTnGGPmhFaaQteYRP04HkR1Xe85cT/pVszA05@Glw/iQx@SgepxeOnEQdqmVPeMCFJYPw@NASRxBBLSABEZJ4pMZGYCa0sj3A4gLM8iWpj4LL3zyGPMECAIE5heejCIdZYz/FkJu1MMrUYLyNMEYxy2E/XZAzN9kn4bqBmVqcWmqXcdX4ff2cZsw1Q3A8PNWEQ/a8xS8InjAf3Q8bIpDO1KDCnQ0i061P3EdclS604NcwPjItB5GYfdF7hYDKmG5vbQvgsSZECTy9WCPIypAJEVfQKYF5ytIavpmLoZhPnC7nadqSGNVp4JLsYCbW7PKxIbjoszqrS8luffg3TZOTwm24ePiO24NBcwvnrkifcDd0ZMe4HLwhqFZtqe5fyP/fwAB5esQzQtiq3m2io0EkFw@xjvT3nmvubFtqPjAySkwNslrLxHQgZemZLRDQ3HtxPzLBORAkatKaan4XsGHYe3DJrJ1GzXGNfXN0DfFrYODKGPaJtjjLB0yvxnSuiBEZ1R12WTGESxzhTRS8b/cgY79YIXzmT4GZA/Z4VdqCxtAeTIwJ3Vj8b1a8/yuOmZXirhRCuVcKKZ8JNOMHMwGE0s0ckz7npB7PiB55iBjwvexSAIY/L4cGe3c7T59KB5KutJFOqu09V9ENmBbThxaXQqo0SEZOPLxIx1Ki@mjT1jvjub4TuLh8WaFZZRlnxwhr8jczZdxxxfpw2E6LCd0HAQUnjOWq1/mhjWD7HjFyO@KZlra6mctTUddngaX@Jzhm407ofozvimZEaXXjeAgZP8xPUCPxB7V9fGb4VecNZZWwCjZlUeUI1thdD/y62NUq5pW2H3plEqiff0GOpFGushdakRUQGd3pXpIP5Btgxuc9weFnWBY6XCbNHPGoJDYhWKTYqnfgPSqsWKwlYxqyixfMN62sSiJhhQXykiRVGthNSwFLXO@BUTS@QgtBRTbTWXl7A0571Gbek@9kyYjDHIKDZadxaK1IUy3i7eKVxxquv1Ypn6VrNYhMIqtaihM1saOtp16p/6R6yYqmOzyKp5UV0JBvnUP4GCijhQirEyar598vTBYRvpH9OLGA4M0TmcCbwEDhloDb0wKZSQWOCxerZVW17@MW8u1pb1WrXOO6W7VVXlxW4FhRUKaf2IPVnCChJNfRWBtGKkP9cJfPRizrfMkHpWAmKlD4unXiiMPM2r/7dvhxgcfVG70jRS6D@Zf6ZtkKPn/V/@8tnGRnWHVHfk/pADP@2T0rN7RH40/4hQFwLw6HCbHB/uUBruLVyX4HOyqOv6qUT0EinAD2wn1Dc8SI8FBcOHhxAC7g1MfWFBh8RWWem9Xm80iruHe0VSaLVOpVoJhJCpz@GppC@SH/V65r7nfPKjTz9dD4JAdoN9ef3HzepHx/O1GgAarICUCha1cc04xvqQf3R9Uyo4NiBIp2MO3CTCr667ErEVdT2vStcdIOUnqIYJ264TtHTdzEktlUCurlMJUizOmwuqIbEcOwOdVkZaD7f@ZrvTyRun0aETm/RF9zBllOCY5/hwJOLBVI5VfVEXIMdjuxEYVGFGrUPtXTkPnZjqi4v6@rW@eN2QWoQMpbW1NcK/oya2ho2WNCQEXDQqMcrp5/7lsjZskA0UUXi@P5wKwUZZ3pI7sPMAz4YEgGHjpCO3c@VkKxNWrr7aaCBNq9DIl1It8ny4sF@t1tAORijfX9Noz09suiWTznTgh2xMjHSjwEE5nvCp3BnCsRFEVmswOvLOT6NVA7rq/sKQExY2ymOfjUJOsmUkP5U7jGHEcesnP5DYd0aswDs/HNPzHknjn5zUAT0G94/tI@MD2Ci8VzaEfihD8CCWe3JZTuDrw9eEbwzfAL4OfC250SIhrC9WcO6T@DxgHZfauNhRcgk1WHBOkgHpwVnA51QzgcgGkLgPINYJnV4/ZhIFfZ6XtbtuQrmqCTmskVP/AdTvsPyDhGR8I4lsJH@x7egDsGWmu2YL@Gs8J1Uejoe9QnBpvrpu3/zDP/3vd//2@o@uEZih0d9@/V83X37zOvt38/d/d/P5v3//e3j86St4jGA3n/8GIL/@l5svv7v5/Lfs@ZubX/8rthn@za@wKf4z5lHvzWe5noC9/vpPX73@Out@/4cZjIzu23GuN58j9bcgkqkdFyNIPgNjvvwmJXjzq9ffChLoff/7UfvNZ9AGQvZ/rMkEAPEfmMIUzmHf4uC//O7116//h216WgN/Sq12I22WGrlnqwWYhkCUKi0N/mtapdHQ8FMppQjebWkpHkhbLWX0UfGfenWd/ee9FJPhThTlpH3STmnaKnQ5kv0CFtGAYHAmGgHAATSMCmlVQX1FtOtOU1bldWVebUb0F@u4Gb1yaUy684CQm4MkPo7DBUWW5@XIh6NCbBz1fGOrJKulkuM7sey69CwyDhT5SpN0/eDgoXW@8pMXrx4sLi8PH@1r15qmYnb@@avf/s55EXgUGzf//PWfv/rH/86fx6D/zc0X/3nzxe9uvviPjfKZIa@mS6P/sfzWDgOPvISTGeH75KIk9kssQ1buSnbTNbyuZRC/zgpLv1wMu1lhKVnNbhHPv6cXto3fYslWihVWyEOpVFRL3eIIxdvFyosANmZb2VOxZt2DYuCEl6vlIi@voMFvRKCRvywttlXJbJqBB7VmFAXdF8paeWd37@Hm092dsvZo81nnZ1sPnh4jrPNo91Hn4e4nuw/LVZWXeAofUaW7cpf6qE8xK6ksxVJLZsWG0qavqOVucUOHIVqUUcFYozh0BkqxWVTVtwWyc3isuc4ZJRerK8SDWHmGS6iXuEaMd9oTF@JQ8eFVcnZ7fh6EZxHp05CWsQg@d@AUhDAs3cGpLoovg/fDEK9pu0kv4kKA1gpo5Be5CCEBL7yhNOwaXfeS@FgoxwGUzDFURcAxuhRnqD51B6Aw7gsKVBD3nYgYXRihwe6Xy8SIzohH0ytwE/0P9TsJbLaiw493KYp0APpcgNk3IF1hd5XS9IkuI4nlFj/KBG4kEowMjDB2DFeSmCW50wrPLNBP7Lo0B6PqhYZHmsROk82jXgBHhyY5eQymtBdX7t1bXhHQk6V7K3X4lsAMRfCqbaAVbcmibtaWQtpz8N42AoKr4oOjYp1UL6DwKJPi8YNcZ/sZ61Sre3tlaa64g13UjXRHo/bOg7QNRJspD5OwlWPZSlmuJds1elz59h4A9ww4awHFYb7zab5znO8cZZ1rScIqmYZhECpe1FOZ5zDbbXn3yZPDJ3VyBeBr@MnGPB9ey6o0BxGCw7YTKzWVC4EjcAcD0cFDlIKSsAFGCg9nAk7QY@02u/BnJJABOKy6sKMItZaZxJheic/LdksIKYLiCTmk1CQ1hMZJ6DN5E@ac4/ETzXEDMGbCSmmu78yCCnEKYBsNsqqSEnEDSXqyu3@MCYRR4vHF8LHnFntCWHmkeCrw4LaR72Dz4R7yXqUxVrgQFge1TApk8yGgtjlqexy1/TBNH4WrG6F2ELXFUVvjqC1EsUQTup6GiVB1gExHI1UZZhsxLImFpgyzg5idByNFGWbrQBKJBIth4A7ZDV3orTKvh14ZwD0Y@RiytoJuxoUpcvwoNnyTKkgKKwlyARtwpG47Cb02C/wYjPbaWaCElhlWoCIQyNqzIr21ebyLIT1JIwjxKpO0t5P2jsZwR3lcCs3RphIwy2EZ7KQ5y@0/PuHWwHl1lXxEVtvMPDZVUjhsndwFHAJEzFmcrEmWmYv40JlAcFCZ5DVJc3j/gmS4b4GgKjRxw0QvwuKMw0YupEDJo1mFfp2akokf0TgjQgEObAAhNWMxM4lhmrAT4gQVKkvNCaGpLXfAGNjIbVuS5vKDqma2eNhdYd10lBPTeXKwc9lwMw7UxZMCkTk9NUaWznBu62ReqOSOMHJKU6bIiCIKG1IqduldUrnVt0pNV6xVBUCdIOyAUzFrJ@ZHhgP2ZOBSPlNor0z6cExhUyylAIRlxAbPeJgDgFG5u5E07wFGBinHNq38@PL4j1J0ihXCR2u70NvmShg6TSIWHpZHtox7MV/ZMaHS3IlB/NVISL26dME2mbwN3EnRuJPKDPVXuypwrXd5KkoRZaKwkaV7AvIJ16h51@UYGD2n5MFnpCnltP/ADvCN04NNb5UpG22vXOQHpUe6jIowjU3EHxSpbOrnwjQdomxcbK@dmRxsv53CgIdqwiBgFeYQWK6A/P8vjSa3c5FQY379kIzKNqlZbs0FEATzCI77ZRI9ml3cO1P43OycmTAwlhkY5lPA9h0xUpFUqXgxxrRLWqDkvl0fAbRmqlb4L8Xk5YGR7xZozxJ5q9BR7o9kCkIhInXWGDlY8R76lAMDGnZemGYn6sN5QoEzruXg0YVzurNqBLY/upmDsD3yjYN/uRcy6mRGdQrkedUOHPVqK53lYMAKkyg0a5BzUTy7QkI0YLJR8mUAoSrHLk1gx/YbHFGUuCibCVrEn6V8DQ2KJzKWcwArO2Sc4AmjndcxzquSeWY3sGQcn3KOHH9@/BdByCtDYC@jPZMDX2XjxnWeUfRESyXPeRtYVLEoDuDEnc6S@tjR4PiI2cDdhT2VaLhFZ9M9T1ienHGp@GAgysexvTQnFCydPt6gSFSOq9Zt@HRycpppw6fJl6Tp3VBkFJzX2NzDvxuHySC@JYdzeMzeJVZwZec4vi3NIGP1Ep7DudhVJX@aUMVpAuVzGuSprrHVWryv1STFIiuYLCscxQROF6xYPO87LmXCePnm03MgMvuhwpQhk8oIOT8/7vFCkZGC9AU4lHRhSzhjCKEVCAGPEH6i5eD0T5D53VpsKsWPfceDUgEvLNhLfPFSjWQvzsHOgm22pxRzK/qtzMKHwJd1MmaJBS4R7zKyQyE42qoTfltWF7sS93Mva2MOT07xMrIuV@u52cVB994v7fksaQUw@W4VNFUv7u3h65AwnC51g3OUurI6kiom30yDVtbqU8sdQ9xfGQmYXIrzCw5s/bnVhAs1rfoo4/HImXZMfjQUV43QqZNcBTYq63DSqYLLoh/MpY24cMzTbCNPCJaMPBi8U4lYYFQJT2ZwoqIX5fSARv3Eo6EBkxcPeDi92Suv7FCTyx4kfekMlNDwe1TByJUhcCvwXIVD0kneQ4JPjDztiRFlXWZxm5U3@SQ9EScaZiS7GOP3cEqOiNkOS@fYjGb4WQtSHF6ikr7hWy47GY@pYx2oCPHv9zCLfkIvd3Gi5WacnPhnPv4BJsdX59MN@lntJ@Qr6tvJC8PsrtDkh@/0orASDVxYD4unPkxVvPdD/IkGy3UBOKLE4xeflL@Jy99JccRlJoVIw1aObyZI/LUQECxvRk59tVSvL5Xqd@8val55XZaytVGWefTL5njYOTsrEZr8DQpteYlngYuUqLcuSmYYk6tCfeLUI40RuydOm9OPVkNcUqOP1u6VlpfSO23@qigXJZfFy63/Bw)

Next answer must not exceed 2922 bytes.

### Explanation

The usual **Brain-Flak** and **Somme** fixes.. Now the interesting part is how to distinguish **Functoid** from the other fungeoids:

**Functoid** ends up taking the same path as **Befunge-96** but the behaviour is different when it occurs `<>v^` in a string, thus the `"v"@` section terminates **Befunge-96** whereas **Functoid** follows the `v`..

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .1+///          
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 4f5c 0a2f 2a20 1b67          O\./* .g
000000b0: 6763 476d 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f  gcGmiV.ZZ;ooo"lo
000000c0: 4722 3b3f 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22  G";?=0%S!11ooo<"
000000d0: 3e3c 3e22 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243  ><>".#define S"C
000000e0: 2220 2020 2020 2020 2f2f 410a 2369 6664  "       //A.#ifd
000000f0: 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573 2f2f  ef __cplusplus//
00000100: 6c0a 2066 2829 3b20 2020 2020 2020 2020  l. f();         
00000110: 2020 202f 2f69 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c     //i.#include<
00000120: 6373 7464 696f 3e2f 2f63 0a23 6465 6669  cstdio>//c.#defi
00000130: 6e65 2053 222b 2b43 2220 2f2f 650a 2069  ne S"++C" //e. i
00000140: 6e74 2f2f 2f20 2020 2020 2020 2020 220a  nt///         ".
00000150: 2365 6e64 6966 2f2f 2020 2020 2020 205c  #endif//       \
00000160: 2e0a 2369 6664 6566 205f 5f4f 424a 435f  ..#ifdef __OBJC_
00000170: 5f0a 2364 6566 696e 6520 5322 432d 6576  _.#define S"C-ev
00000180: 6974 6365 6a62 4f22 0a23 656e 6469 660a  itcejbO".#endif.
00000190: 206d 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2853   main(){printf(S
000001a0: 292f 2a2f 6d61 696e 2829 7b69 6d70 6f72  )/*/main(){impor
000001b0: 7420 7374 642e 7374 6469 6f3b 2244 222e  t std.stdio;"D".
000001c0: 7772 6974 652f 2a2a 2f3b 7d2f 2a7d 3c0a  write/**/;}/*}<.
000001d0: 3e20 2076 0a39 3939 2039 3939 2039 390a  >  v.999 999 99.
000001e0: 3939 3920 3939 3920 390a 3939 3976 3c3e  999 999 9.999v<>
000001f0: 0a76 2020 3c3e 2265 6675 6e67 652d 3938  .v  <>"efunge-98
00000200: 222c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 3779 332d 763c  ",,,,,,,,,7y3-v<
00000210: 2040 0a3e 2020 235e 4776 2020 2020 2020   @.>  #^Gv      
00000220: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2040 2c22 4222             @,"B"
00000230: 5f22 5472 222c 2c40 0a20 2020 763c 5b5f  _"Tr",,@.   v<[_
00000240: 225d 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3933 223e 2c2c  "]Befunge-93">,,
00000250: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 307c 403c 0a20 2020  ,,,,,,,,0|@<.   
00000260: 3e23 3c22 4265 6675 6e67 652d 3936 223e  >#<"Befunge-96">
00000270: 205e 7624 4730 3031 0a76 2020 2c2c 2c2c   ^v$G001.v  ,,,,
00000280: 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6542 2220 5f20  ,"79-egnufeB" _ 
00000290: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002a0: 2076 3c0a 3e20 202c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2020   v<.>  ,,,,,@#  
000002b0: 2020 2020 2c22 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572      ,"79-egnufer
000002c0: 5422 5f76 2320 2447 3030 3031 3c3e 0a20  T"_v# $G0001<>. 
000002d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000002e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c 3e31               <>1
000002f0: 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2023 402c  0000G$v.     #@,
00000300: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c40 2322  ,,,,,,,,,,,,,@#"
00000310: 3739 2d65 676e 7566 6572 6461 7551 225f  79-egnuferdauQ"_
00000320: 3130 3030 3030 4724 760a 2020 2020 2020  100000G$v.      
00000330: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000340: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2c2c 2237 392d 6567          ,,"79-eg
00000350: 6e75 6665 746e 6975 5122 5f31 3030 3030  nufetniuQ"_10000
00000360: 3030 4724 2176 402c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c  00G$!v@,,,,,,,,,
00000370: 2c2c 2c0a 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ,,,.            
00000380: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000390: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000003a0: 2237 392d 6567 6e75 6665 7470 6553 225f  "79-egnufetpeS"_
000003b0: 2253 6578 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3722 2340  "Sexefunge-97"#@
000003c0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4023 2c0a  ,,,,,,,,,,,,@#,.
000003d0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000003e0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 203c                 <
000003f0: 3e22 7622 400a 2040 2c22 4622 2c22 7522  >"v"@. @,"F","u"
00000400: 2c22 6e22 2c22 6322 2c22 7422 2c22 6f22  ,"n","c","t","o"
00000410: 2c22 6922 2c22 6422 3c3e 2072 6564 2064  ,"i","d"<> red d
00000420: 6f77 6e20 7477 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674  own two red left
00000430: 206f 6e65 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2067   one yellow up g
00000440: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77  reen down yellow
00000450: 2075 7020 6772 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2072   up green down r
00000460: 6564 2075 7020 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420  ed up three red 
00000470: 7269 6768 7420 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77  right two yellow
00000480: 2064 6f77 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77   down yellow dow
00000490: 6e20 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565  n blue left gree
000004a0: 6e20 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  n down red down 
000004b0: 6f6e 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  one yellow down 
000004c0: 626c 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20  blue left green 
000004d0: 646f 776e 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20 7477  down red down tw
000004e0: 6f20 7265 6420 6c65 6674 206f 6e65 2079  o red left one y
000004f0: 656c 6c6f 7720 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  ellow up yellow 
00000500: 646f 776e 2062 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2067  down blue left g
00000510: 7265 656e 2064 6f77 6e20 7265 6420 6c65  reen down red le
00000520: 6674 206f 6e65 2072 6564 2064 6f77 6e20  ft one red down 
00000530: 7468 7265 6520 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77  three yellow dow
00000540: 6e20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c  n yellow down bl
00000550: 7565 206c 6566 7420 6772 6565 6e20 646f  ue left green do
00000560: 776e 2072 6564 2075 7020 7477 6f20 6772  wn red up two gr
00000570: 6565 6e20 646f 776e 2079 656c 6c6f 7720  een down yellow 
00000580: 7570 2079 656c 6c6f 7720 646f 776e 2062  up yellow down b
00000590: 6c75 6520 6c65 6674 2072 6564 2075 7020  lue left red up 
000005a0: 7468 7265 6520 7265 6420 7269 6768 7420  three red right 
000005b0: 7477 6f20 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20  two yellow down 
000005c0: 7965 6c6c 6f77 2064 6f77 6e20 626c 7565  yellow down blue
000005d0: 206c 6566 740a 2e4c 2020 2020 2020 2020   left..L        
000005e0: 2020 2020 2020 2e20 2a2f 2f2f 7b7d 5de2        . *///{}].
000005f0: 8e9a efbc a6c2 b96c 616f 6372 6168 43c2  .......laocrahC.
00000600: abe2 96b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 c2b2 e28c  ................
00000610: 82e2 86a8 ceb1 e286 a8c3 9fe2 86a8 c2b2  ................
00000620: c2b2 e28c 82e2 86a8 e286 90c3 9fe2 89a4  ................
00000630: e296 bce2 8692 e296 bce2 8690 e289 a5e2  ................
00000640: 8692 e28c 82e2 86a8 cf83 e286 92e2 8692  ................
00000650: e286 92e2 86a8 c39f e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
00000660: 92e2 86a8 cf80 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2  ................
00000670: 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 c39f c2a1 e286  ................
00000680: 92e2 8692 e286 a8ce b4e2 8692 e286 a8c3  ................
00000690: 9fe2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8  ................
000006a0: c2b5 e286 92e2 8692 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
000006b0: cf86 e286 a8ce b5cf 80e2 8c82 e286 a8c2  ................
000006c0: a1c3 9fc2 a1e2 8692 e286 92e2 8692 e286  ................
000006d0: a8c2 a1cf 80cf 83e2 96b2 e28c 82e2 86a8  ................
000006e0: c2a1 cf83 c2b5 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1  ................
000006f0: ceb1 c2a1 e286 92e2 86a8 c2a1 cf80 c2a1  ................
00000700: e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2 a1e2 96b2 e296  ................
00000710: b2e2 96b2 c2a1 cf83 e296 b2c2 a1ce b4c2  ................
00000720: a1cf 86e2 96b2 e296 b2e2 96b2 e296 b2c2  ................
00000730: a1ce b5e2 96bc e296 bcc2 a1c2 bb2b 2b2b  .............+++
00000740: 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b  +[-<+++++>]<[-<+
00000750: 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b  +++++<+++++<++++
00000760: 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e  +>>>]<<<+++++++.
00000770: 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e  >-.>---.<<-----.
00000780: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e  ++++++++.-----.>
00000790: 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828  --.>---.<+.>>>((
000007a0: 2828 2828 2828 2828 2829 2829 2829 297b  ((((((((()()()){
000007b0: 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29  }){}){}){}()){})
000007c0: 2828 2829 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d  ((()()()()){}){}
000007d0: 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829  )[(([][]){}){}()
000007e0: 5d29 285b 5d28 2929 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929  ])([]()){})[]())
000007f0: 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28 295d 285b 5d28 2928  (([[][]()]([]()(
00000800: 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d  (((([][][])){}{}
00000810: 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929 295b 5d28 2929 287b  )[]){})))[]())({
00000820: 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922 3b28 2129 3d73 6571   -}_=")";(!)=seq
00000830: 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65 7420 6221 5f3d 2222  ;main|let b!_=""
00000840: 3d70 7574 5374 7224 2822 2221 2273 6e72  =putStr$(""!"snr
00000850: 6574 7461 5067 6e61 422b 2229 2b2b 696e  ettaPgnaB+")++in
00000860: 6974 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 2822 7b2d 0a2f  it"lleksaH("{-./
00000870: 2f48 484c 6477 364b 6a7c 492a 3333 764d  /HHLdw6Kj|I*33vM
00000880: 472d 7d2d 2d29 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a  G-}--)*///....ij
00000890: 6f6d 65f0 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d  ome...........Em
000008a0: 6f74 696e 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f  otinomicon......
000008b0: aae2 8fac e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65  .......@,ka"89-e
000008c0: 676e 7566 656e 5522                      gnufenU"
```

Answer (score 1):

## 26. dash, 884 bytes

```
void /*-{-- #hR!X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5 "M!M elif MOC SODeerF$}++++[*///\
 /+ #\
 basename "$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)"|rev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
1+///\
/*ggcGmiVZZ;ooo"loG";?=0%S!11ooo<"><>"
#define S"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
 f();
#include<cstdio>
#define S"++C"
 int
#endif
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define S"C-evitcejbO"
#endif
 main(){printf(S)/*/main(){import std.stdio;"D".write/**/;}/*}<<
 "rT";#z_"B",@>2+;  >    ][ v;#;8k,7y2-;@,,<<<
>"Befunge-96"#^Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,,,,,,,,,@{
Sc0}\Y6m:Hq(Gruz!+*///)]⎚¿⁵laocrahC¦++++[-<+++++>]<[-<++++++<+++++<+++++>>>]<<<+++++++.>-.>---.<<-----.++++++++.-----.>--.>---.<+.>>>((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}()){})((()()()()){}){})[(([][]){}){}()])([]()){})[]())(([[][]()]([]()((((([][][])){}{})[]){})))[]())({ -}_=")";(!)=seq;main|let b!_=""=putStr$(""!"snrettaPgnaB+")++"lleksaH"-- *///💬ijome💬➡😭Emotinomicon😲⏪⏬⏩@,ka"89-egnufenU"
```

Prints:

- `D` in D
- `emmoS` in Somme
- `><>` in ><>
- `C` in C
- `laocrahC` in Charcoal
- `miV` in Vim
- `C-evitcejbO` in Objective-C
- `89-egnufeB` in Befunge-98
- `39-egnufeB` in Befunge-93
- `elif MOC SODeerF` in FreeDOS COM file
- `><>loG` in Gol><>
- `89-egnufenU` in Unefunge-98
- `79-egnufeB` in Befunge-97
- `69-egnufeB` in Befunge-96
- `kcufniarb` in brainfuck
- `89-egnuferT` in Trefunge-98
- `kalf-niarb` in brain-flak
- `hsab` in bash
- `lleksaH` in Haskell
- `hsz` in zsh
- `ijome` in emoji
- `snrettaPgnaB+lleksaH` in Haskell+BangPatterns
- `++C` in C++
- `nocimonitomE` in Emotinomicon
- `hsk` in ksh
- `hsad` in dash

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rRrLctvI8Sz8Qi4jUGsAIkCQlC3LFMlYT8uJbaks7cYxRXNBYEDCwoPBQ6KsVaryA9mqnFI5JJVLqpJKLqnKOVX5FH9B/sDpnhmA4MO7W0loi5yZfkxPd08/QA6tZPzpU4XsOQ6xCB1Z2Si0XpA0gtkk8m9HfpSSlCYpGVtxSJOEDG/JK48efqDvr6KhVCEHke9bk4QS@SByqEys0CHyXjzKAhqmiUwSaqdeFCbEjWIypGlKY0KnExp7NLSpJNlWSrrEBlrJD4mRsCF7qw1dUiH71M3CETWebElplNljMok9YCzB1p5LbqOMWCh7vqFOAuuKkiSLKZ4iiBzPvSUgQW1yS5KIpGPYLx3TWyChxAttP3OoAwNcJL4XXknUHkfECIm80ZBBNE5bWm3iqhMl86tbuJpEQUAN15siTJrcpuMo3FpYfbH36tmXe8@OBs9fHR696TSk/Z9fHJ135A31xiaG3caja7IEp2aKI74VjjJrRFXtTlpj@8kVsjHPpUY2GjrZYJzAQmAwOcd9nYWhF44IO8yDprQ2BJPDPuwg3ShLJ1kqcMWZv4npdRdNZKfUydksrhuhL62BAdaJHUwIZ0NyIHnwYDUAqHZR0aG0xvn@LI5ANo5VIyd06mTBpAXQ6dQhuXCuJ60taA20pS7ooNrQtOLUBrn8ekNF3@JMtMuv0cZMCd3che7RicZpOklapjny0nE2rNlRYF7Et8/T0xCcgZppfOulUT6m1AysBFzYvImtCThxAhxyAxEZL4pMZCYCG0sz2CEAnMAhRpyFzL3LwHP0EECIM7heZjRJTeYz/L0WD5cIuu0uoOcOxihcLxmzN/T0RfwDwGZYtpHatjn0QhM@VwtzAFfdjiy/IBHzYrBqg6@8APCvvaC4wjCupeACXdOh12aY@T5pdh800DfQLgJc5nE6fI/B4poaKO4I5ZuSqFi0OV8jKq@xLYBlzVxYLDMuYshOfqZhscJ04Q6H3tKRZpFngYqRwJjL8w1JLc/HG1XdelKmPwZ3OTw9JwenL4nr@bRkMB49ysjPIn@FTUeRz8yaxHY@XqX8L8PyASe3bEIMI0mdzpMdGGQC4fNnfLykmcdGkLqeiW/AIV/8PIft7@FQLG8v8RjGlhe6mX1VsMgXZqMloov4ew6dxp85NONpuL41v9/Ygv32cXRiif2IsTdHCKFT5h9LTE@s5Ir6PrvEwIpNlpA@MPoPK8hpEL33Fs3PFvn7KrOLLav7sHJmYWYNk/n9jTdl2PJNr1bxolWreNFs@MgvmD2ZzC6WmJQJj4Io9cIo8OwoxIA3nURxSl6dHh4NzvYuTjqXspklsel7QzMElgNIw5lPk0sZOeJKcb6Czdyk9n5Z2Cumu6sVunO4WZyZWSQW4V2iXIbtSUy7LKl2lSIjY/rDesTGpBBNaKgqiKFotZhajqq1GL1qY4kRxY5qa93OVhNLGz5rN5qPcWbDYVLgobS7DxTqQxXkKg8qdxzpflfRaeh0FAXyUi5Q22SitE0U6zK8DM9YLmrhUGHFkEhOgkC@DHuQj4gHmYxlofV@7@L5aR/xX9FpCvVWcgMlVZBBjYbC0KlNIQNjfmTlQLextfVjPtxsbJmNeotPqg/rmsZrhRoyq1Ty9IszWcIEjKJ@kwA3JTHfmQReplJSLROkVWRQLJTA98xKZaZoXjx9@nQdeQ4xN407wyCV8ev1N8ZTcvZu/Mtfvnn6tH5I6ofy@Jovvh2T6ptHRH65/pJQH/T/8vSAnJ8eUhofb9xX4dXbNE3zUiJmlVTgA24jDa0A/GBDRethDUdAvZFtbmyYdArFFFYuu612Wzk6PVZIpdu9lBpVxsTc/NFoZD8LvK9@9PbtbhRFsh89k3d/3Kl/cb7eaMBCm@VaqeJQF7RPziGVShXPhSkZDOyJnyX4JxFX1XYBwAvKtg1RyIu6JbJqFQjBVVKpAk7huTMmp/s/ORgMyjsY9NpLbfp@eCrn2FDWeiGUgFz76rlmbppiyQvY7YMda2zXXag1ajexl1Jzc9PcvTc379ttCeLChbxb@TCQ92X9abdZ3SVQsMKr3yPXu5XdnSv98W3T2H2q621A75YDe@Xd23r9WeXdYOOh0W1Uu3rxenonndv1@8ufbwetk1@oz@Lsw3oV7aP1P/76d//658df/cO3Iju2xgf/@hMzntHGj2q3386H1XbpvdsFSFsAqrWuAf8No9ZuG/iqVXMAn3aNHA6o3a46e2n4T7u7L/7zWQ4pYD1V7fV7/Rynr8GUA9knQBEMALbOWOMCUAAOw0JcTWDfEeN@0JE1eVdd1zoJ/cUu2ugbn6ZkuA4AuQO16Hkab6iyvC4nYQz9kHUGLdd@VdYgGPs@vUqsExluCSrx33/4zV@991FAcfDx93/89x9@@7dy6IX53z9@@5eP3/7147d/fqpfWfLOE4OOwsyl4ZfyJzeOAvIBgjDhLrIpCVfBK7P9UHI7vhUMHYuELRYDQ12Jh0UMlJzOUMFUdzl1XfxTqq6q1FhnBtda0apDZQbiY6X2PgKfdNVjDcPrMfh7j0dWXeGhAAa8@IFBuS9S@ppkd6D6hriYJFDLqU/0w6PjF3sXR4e68XLvzeBn@88vznFt8PLo5eDF0VdHL/S6xsORyk9UG24/hK4S9lPtWs5LdbSqXXPhko5VTR8qT004okMZFpw1SWNvoiodRdOgD4Z6zfA9aCCnO9sk8EIvsHxCg8y3UmxfF3pfiE7YNRaN8k0UXyVkTGOqY8C@8SAF4xpmGVCqj@x10H4cY0c2zEYJZwK4TkSTUOEsBAfsbSGMDa2hf0tCDOrQ0ELIh4AAFLP@l4HG1J/AhulYYOAG6dhLiDWEE1qsldQJlAUkoHm3a6P@IdeQCLIcRB74CG5FQoHFkDOAqh/cEiKBlLtPcptIzLdYjxpFfiIcjEysOPUsX5KYJKXEyj0L9icudHdwqlFsBaRD3NzZAkj/kOY6pPcKROlvbj96tLUtVnvNR9st@KuCGKqg1fqAK8aSQ/1iLMV05GGLlgDCnfL8TGmR@rRRr@tEOX9emhy8YZN6/fhYl9aUQ5zi3oh3NhsfPs/HgLSX0zAO@yWS/ZzkXoLCcsQ3PziGxWML6gLAOC1P3pYn5@XJWTGB9hQTBI3jKFaDZKQxzaG3u/LR69enr1vkDpbv4aM483p8L2vSGlioRqdeqjY0zmRE0wEaYoAJX0VOOAAhhYYLBj3UWL/PenuGAh6Ax2oJORRIqHaWontlIc9YjmCiwMYLfEi1Qxq4mmZxyPgtiHODpRKK40cgzIKU0trYW7Uq2KkAbbfJjkaqxI8k6fXRs3N0ILQSty@aj73vs3cwK7cUdwVu3D7Sney9OEbau9zGKmfC7KDppEL2XgDogIMO5kEHL3L3Ufl2M9AhgvY5aH8etI8g5mhir4s4E1udINHZbKsCcoAQ5sRipwJyiJDD57ONCsj@iSQcCYJh5F@zYjwOdpjW40CH5RGcfA7Y2EY1Y2BKvDBJrdCmKqJCJEEqIAOKXG29OOgzw8@t0VG/MJTYZYUUuBEwZONVlt7fOz9Ck/ZyC4K9dJLPDvPZ2RzsrAzLV0u4OQf0cgiDg9xnufznPS6NaZId8gXZ6TPx2FXJ1yF1chXwFUBiyuJoHbLFVMSPzhiCgnRS3klaw14B0TBvAaM6DDFhohYhOOOxkQoxkPPsVqFel65kFiZQYBTHAAYeJICY2qm4mcSybciEeEHFltXOAtNclgcgDCRy15WktfKh6oUsAU632TQ/5cJ1XjzsWnHcggL34k6BwNI@DYaW33Au66JfaOSBEHJpp2IjK0koJKScbfO7uHKpP8s1j1g70F6MBlE8AKWi1y7cjwIG5NnEp/ym0JFOxt5ozK5YjgEAx0ot7vFwBwCicXUjalkDDA1cjiWt8vnK8C9ycA4VzGexXezb55swcO5EzDzMj1wZczGP7OhQue@kwP5uxqRVb05ZkinLwJWUzCtJZ6D/WVWR73yXppIcoBOVnSzPCUgnVKOVVVciYPgckxufoeaYy/oDOUA33giS3g7bbJZeOcsf5B55GBVmmruI/5WliqtfMtOyiYpzsVy70jlYvl2CgIYaQiAgFeIQCFeA/v9zo8V0LhxqTq8/xKOKJLVKrSUDAmNuwXm9LIJnt4trZwleup0rHQbOsgLCdArQsSdOKpwqZy/OmE@hVa9PH7ut2YLRybcV@sshZX4g5HczdFex/CzTme/PeApEwSJX1hw6SPE9@DkFGjQevLftQTKGfkKFHtfxsHXhlP6qGoHlR79QEI5nuvHwIb3g0SIrqlNAL2/tQavX2B5sRRNWmCSx3QCfS9LVFRKCAVKckocBXNU4tLkAncs3eKIk85E3Y7SJH81yDQ0bL3gspwBS1mT0sMPol/eYp9XIOpMbSAqKt5yiRF8@/zSKeWUI5DrKs3jwHXZujPMMYyRGGnnHx0CiiaA4gY47vyWtudbg/IzJwNWFM40YmKKL615G1BdvXM4@mojycS6XlpiCpMvtDbLEzTFqfQ6eX06Osyz4MnpTWs6GwqOgX2N3LwSCOJukn/HhEhy9t8kKrqKP42lpBRqrl7AP52x31HI3oYluAvlzHKSpP2HRWnw12yGKwgomx4lnNoHughWLN2PPp4wZL99CegNI9jhW2WZIpDFETs/bPV4oMlTgvgFNyRBSwhUDiF0BEeC4wjtavpw/Li9na5FUlC9DL4BSAR9YsO/r02aDFN@RQ2bBMcspSimif5ZY6BDoiklBLDHDZeJnC6wpBEU7LcKflrVEVuJ6HhVj9OHFK64j6Va9VbpdfOnR93N7t4pbBUR@WIed6tNHx/jLBzjOkPrRDXLd3plxFZdvpUDbT1pL4Y4BHm/PGCyG4nLAgdRfiiacqe20Zh6PLWc@sXlrKB41wqRFShXYrKzDS6cJKof@YCpjRoVnXiabaUKQFOjR5Ds3EQFGk7Azg46KTvW8QaNhFtDYgsuLDR5eb/brFtbUlLwHUT94EzW2whFV0XI6GG4b3negSeqVNSToxMnzmThRMWUS91l5U3bSnuhomJDswRh/DqeWkJjsEDrnbjSDrwpIaXyLm4yt0PFZZzy3HZtARYjfNcEt@im9PcKLVrpxchZehdFNWKZr8esG86L2E/xV7dPiA8PiWaHNm@/8QWEtmfgQD5XLEK4qPvdDeM@AcF0BiiQL@INPyn90w7/Q9MTDTAqWhlSO36JJqRXDoYGxvJd4rZ1qq9Wsth4@3jQCfVeWitgoy9z6uj1vdk7OSoQO/7bP2GpyL/ARE/dtiZIZzuRrUJ94rcRgyH7P63P8WTTEkJp88eRRdauZP9PmvwrhrGRd/I7lPw)

Next answer must not exceed 1149 bytes.

### Hexdump

```
00000000: 766f 6964 202f 2a2d 7b2d 2d20 2368 5221  void /*-{-- #hR!
00000010: 582d 4020 505e 687e 7e58 4040 3044 2030  X-@ P^h~~X@@0D 0
00000020: 4422 6876 2158 2d40 2050 5a68 202b 5835  D"hv!X-@ PZh +X5
00000030: 2022 4d21 4d20 656c 6966 204d 4f43 2053   "M!M elif MOC S
00000040: 4f44 6565 7246 247d 2b2b 2b2b 5b2a 2f2f  ODeerF$}++++[*//
00000050: 2f5c 0a20 2f2b 2023 5c0a 2062 6173 656e  /\. /+ #\. basen
00000060: 616d 6520 2224 2872 6561 646c 696e 6b20  ame "$(readlink 
00000070: 2f70 726f 632f 2424 2f65 7865 2922 7c72  /proc/$$/exe)"|r
00000080: 6576 3b3a 3c3c 2745 4f46 2720 233e 3e5c  ev;:<<'EOF' #>>\
00000090: 0a31 2b2f 2f2f 5c0a 2f2a 1b67 6763 476d  .1+///\./*.ggcGm
000000a0: 6956 1b5a 5a3b 6f6f 6f22 6c6f 4722 3b3f  iV.ZZ;ooo"loG";?
000000b0: 3d30 2553 2131 316f 6f6f 3c22 3e3c 3e22  =0%S!11ooo<"><>"
000000c0: 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 220a 2369  .#define S"C".#i
000000d0: 6664 6566 205f 5f63 706c 7573 706c 7573  fdef __cplusplus
000000e0: 0a20 6628 293b 0a23 696e 636c 7564 653c  . f();.#include<
000000f0: 6373 7464 696f 3e0a 2364 6566 696e 6520  cstdio>.#define 
00000100: 5322 2b2b 4322 0a20 696e 740a 2365 6e64  S"++C". int.#end
00000110: 6966 0a23 6966 6465 6620 5f5f 4f42 4a43  if.#ifdef __OBJC
00000120: 5f5f 0a23 6465 6669 6e65 2053 2243 2d65  __.#define S"C-e
00000130: 7669 7463 656a 624f 220a 2365 6e64 6966  vitcejbO".#endif
00000140: 0a20 6d61 696e 2829 7b70 7269 6e74 6628  . main(){printf(
00000150: 5329 2f2a 2f6d 6169 6e28 297b 696d 706f  S)/*/main(){impo
00000160: 7274 2073 7464 2e73 7464 696f 3b22 4422  rt std.stdio;"D"
00000170: 2e77 7269 7465 2f2a 2a2f 3b7d 2f2a 7d3c  .write/**/;}/*}<
00000180: 3c0a 2022 7254 223b 237a 5f22 4222 2c40  <. "rT";#z_"B",@
00000190: 3e32 2b3b 2020 3e20 2020 205d 5b20 763b  >2+;  >    ][ v;
000001a0: 233b 386b 2c37 7932 2d3b 402c 2c3c 3c3c  #;8k,7y2-;@,,<<<
000001b0: 0a3e 2242 6566 756e 6765 2d39 3622 235e  .>"Befunge-96"#^
000001c0: 5a30 3047 235e 5f24 342d 3e31 2b3e 2c2c  Z00G#^_$4->1+>,,
000001d0: 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 407b 0a53 6330 7d5c  ,,,,,,,,@{.Sc0}\
000001e0: 5936 6d3a 4871 2847 7275 7a21 2b2a 2f2f  Y6m:Hq(Gruz!+*//
000001f0: 2f29 5de2 8e9a c2bf e281 b56c 616f 6372  /)]........laocr
00000200: 6168 43c2 a62b 2b2b 2b5b 2d3c 2b2b 2b2b  ahC..++++[-<++++
00000210: 2b3e 5d3c 5b2d 3c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b  +>]<[-<++++++<++
00000220: 2b2b 2b3c 2b2b 2b2b 2b3e 3e3e 5d3c 3c3c  +++<+++++>>>]<<<
00000230: 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2e 3e2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  +++++++.>-.>---.
00000240: 3c3c 2d2d 2d2d 2d2e 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b  <<-----.++++++++
00000250: 2e2d 2d2d 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2e3e 2d2d 2d2e  .-----.>--.>---.
00000260: 3c2b 2e3e 3e3e 2828 2828 2828 2828 2828  <+.>>>((((((((((
00000270: 2829 2829 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 297b 7d29  ()()()){}){}){})
00000280: 7b7d 2829 297b 7d29 2828 2829 2829 2829  {}()){})((()()()
00000290: 2829 297b 7d29 7b7d 295b 2828 5b5d 5b5d  ()){}){})[(([][]
000002a0: 297b 7d29 7b7d 2829 5d29 285b 5d28 2929  ){}){}()])([]())
000002b0: 7b7d 295b 5d28 2929 2828 5b5b 5d5b 5d28  {})[]())(([[][](
000002c0: 295d 285b 5d28 2928 2828 2828 5b5d 5b5d  )]([]()((((([][]
000002d0: 5b5d 2929 7b7d 7b7d 295b 5d29 7b7d 2929  [])){}{})[]){}))
000002e0: 295b 5d28 2929 287b 202d 7d5f 3d22 2922  )[]())({ -}_=")"
000002f0: 3b28 2129 3d73 6571 3b6d 6169 6e7c 6c65  ;(!)=seq;main|le
00000300: 7420 6221 5f3d 2222 3d70 7574 5374 7224  t b!_=""=putStr$
00000310: 2822 2221 2273 6e72 6574 7461 5067 6e61  (""!"snrettaPgna
00000320: 422b 2229 2b2b 226c 6c65 6b73 6148 222d  B+")++"lleksaH"-
00000330: 2d20 2a2f 2f2f f09f 92ac 696a 6f6d 65f0  - *///....ijome.
00000340: 9f92 ace2 9ea1 f09f 98ad 456d 6f74 696e  ..........Emotin
00000350: 6f6d 6963 6f6e f09f 98b2 e28f aae2 8fac  omicon..........
00000360: e28f a940 2c6b 6122 3839 2d65 676e 7566  ...@,ka"89-egnuf
00000370: 656e 5522                                enU"
```