# Toilet Paper Mysteries

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Today you need to solve a very practical problem: How many loops do you need to have a certain number of sheets on your toilet paper roll? Let's look at some facts:

- The diameter of a bare toilet paper cylinder is 3.8cm
- The length of one sheet of toilet paper is 10cm.
- The thickness of one sheet of toilet paper is 1mm.

Before you wrap around the cylinder the first time, it has a circumference in cm of 3.8*pi. Every time you wrap a sheet around the cylinder its radius increases by .1, therefore its circumference increases by .2*PI. Use this information to find out how many loops it takes to fit *n* sheets of toilet paper. (Note: Use an approximation of Pi that is at least as accurate as 3.14159).

**Test Cases**:

**n=1**:

- 10/(3.8*pi) = **.838 loops**

**n=2**:

- (How many full loops can we make?) 1 full loop = 3.8*pi = 11.938.
- (How much do we have left after the 1st loop?) 20 - 11.938 = 8.062
- (How much of a 2nd loop does the remaining piece make?) 8.062/(4*pi) = .642 loops
- Answer: **1.642 loops**

**n=3**:

- 1st full loop = 3.8*pi = 11.938, 2nd full loop = 4*pi = 12.566
- 30 - 11.938 - 12.566 = 5.496
- 5.496/(4.2*pi) = .417
- Answer: **2.417 loops**

**n=100** => 40.874

Comment: @FlagAsSpam Because in the first bullet point, I calculate the length of all the full loops.

Comment: Also, your calculations are only correct if the bare roll is `3.7cm` in diameter. Only then the mean diameter of the first layer is `3.8cm`.

Comment: @RainerP. o.k. I changed the language a bit. It should agree with what you're saying.

Comment: Phew! 1mm thick? Are you sure you're using toilet paper and not cardboard?

Comment: I'm getting `2.416499187…` for `n = 3`. That doesn't round to `2.417`. Is my calculation off somewhere?

Comment: @Pietu1998 It's because when doing it by hand I rounded to 3 decimal places.

Comment: So our programs do not have to round?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Nope, less rounding is better.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Clearly you don't know about triple-ply :p

Comment: Under the assumption that the toilet paper does not make *steps* but continuously increases the radius, you can get a closed form approximation to requested result. Is this good enough? `nloops = sqrt(n+11.34)*0.0564189 - 0.19`

Comment: @flawr Sorry, no.

Comment: Aside from the golfing aspect, I find this question incredibly amusing and even useful, lol. I wouldn't be surprised if this became a programming homework question and we see [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) littered with this question!

Comment: Proposed test case: `100` -> `40.874`

Comment: Triple-ply cardboard?! Now *that's* thick!

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I came here because I was expecting something else when I saw "toilet paper mysteries"...

Comment: @Ashwin Yeah, that was part off the idea :p

Comment: I can't get this shit to work. I think I need to try something different. :)

Comment: They see me rolling, they be knockin'.

Comment: It is literally a shit challenge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 23 bytes

```
+fg0=-QJc*.n0+18T50)cQJ
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bfg0%3D-QJc*.n0%2B18T50)cQJ&input=3&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bfg0%3D-QJc*.n0%2B18T50)cQJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A100&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                            Q = input number (implicit)
 f                 )        increment T from 1, for each T:
             +18T             add 18 to T, get radius
         *.n0                 multiply by pi to, get half the circumference
        c        50           divide by 50, get circumference in sheets
       J                      save it to J
    =-Q                       decrement Q by it
  g0                          use this T if Q is now <= 0
+                           add
                     Q        Q (now <= 0)
                    c J       divided by J (the last circumference)
                            and print (implicit)
```

Comment: explanation, please?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Added. Explaining Pyth is always so much fun.

Comment: Your explanation looks like a potential output for [Surfin' Word](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69350/46313)

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell, <s>59</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

A scale factor of 5/pi is applied, so that a paper cylinder has a circumference of 19,20,21... cm and a sheet is 50/pi cm.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to xnor, by using an unnamed function.

```haskell
x!s|s>x=1+(x+1)!(s-x)|1>0=s/x
(19!).(50/pi*)
```

Comment: A pretty recursive method. Note that [unnamed functions are allowed even when you have other lines](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/20260) (despite Haskell not supporting it), so the last line can be pointfree as `(19!).(50/pi*)`.

Comment: Wow, blows my approach out of the water!

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
R+18×3.6°µ0;+\³_÷µḞi0©ị+®’
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UisxOMOXMy42wrDCtTA7K1zCs1_Dt8K14bieaTDCqeG7iyvCruKAmQ&input=&args=Mw)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 97 bytes

```hs
p&((m,x):(n,y):z)|y<p=p&((n,y):z)|1>0=m+(p-x)/(y-x)
t=(&zip[0..](scanl(+)0$map(*pi)[0.38,0.4..]))
```

Might be able to golf it further by moving the filtering from the `&` operator into a `takeWhile` statement, but given that it's not a golfing language this seems relatively competitive.

### Explanation

The stream of lengths of toilet paper that comprise full loops are first calculated as `scanl (+) 0 (map (* pi) [0.38, 0.4 ..]]`. We zip these with the number of full revolutions, which will also pick up the type `Double` implicitly. We pass this to `&` with the current number that we want to calculate, call it `p`.

`&` processes the list of `(Double, Double)` pairs on its right by (a) skipping forward until `snd . head . tail` is greater than `p`, at which point `snd . head` is less than `p`.

To get the proportion of this row that is filled, it then computes `(p - x)/(y - x),` and adds it to the overall amount of loops that have been made so far.

Answer (score 5):

## C++, 72 bytes

```
float f(float k,int d=19){auto c=d/15.9155;return k<c?k/c:1+f(k-c,d+1);}
```

I used C++ here because it supports default function arguments, needed here to initialize the radius.

Recursion seems to produce shorter code than using a `for`-loop. Also, `auto` instead of `float` - 1 byte less!

Comment: You almost fooled me, using `d` for the `r`adius...

Comment: Not sure if you were aware, but this was the 69,420th post on CGCC!

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the number 69420 had any special significance! Too bad I cannot relate it to either C++ or toilet paper.

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 82 bytes

```lua
n=... l,c,p=10*n,11.938042,0 while l>c do l,c,p=l-c,c+.628318,p+1 end print(p+l/c)
```

Not bad for a general-purpose language, but not very competitive against dedicated golfing languages of course.  The constants are premultiplied with pi, to the stated precision.

Comment: OP wasn't specific about what kind of input to accept, so I left out the initialization of `n`, but the rest would've run as-is (as-was?).  In any case, now it takes `n` from the command line; e.g. for 3 sheets run it as `lua tp.lua 3`.

Comment: It's not precisely a rule of this question, but a general policy. Unless the question says otherwise, hardcoding the input makes the submission a snippet, which are [not allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2423). More information about site-wide defaults can be found in the [code golf tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info).

Comment: I knew about the "whole program or function" part but didn't know that "hardcoding the input makes the submission a snippet".  Thanks for clarifying.  I think this would actually be longer as a function!

Answer (score 3):

## C, 87 bytes

```
float d(k){float f=31.831*k,n=round(sqrt(f+342.25)-19);return n+(f-n*(37+n))/(38+2*n);}
```

Uses an explicit formula for the number of whole loops:

```
floor(sqrt(100 * k / pi + (37/2)^2) - 37/2)
```

I replaced `100 / pi` by `31.831`, and replaced `floor` with `round`, turning the annoying number `-18.5` to a clean `-19`.

The length of these loops is

```
pi * n * (3.7 + 0.1 * n)
```

After subtracting this length from the whole length, the code divides the remainder by the proper circumference.

---

Just to make it clear - this solution has complexity `O(1)`, unlike many (all?) other solutions. So it's a bit longer than a loop or recursion.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 77 bytes

```
function w(s,d,c){d=d||3.8;c=d*3.14159;return c>s*10?s*10/c:1+w(s-c/10,d+.2)}
```

```js
function w(s,d,c){d=d||3.8;c=d*3.14159;return c>s*10?s*10/c:1+w(s-c/10,d+.2)}

function wraps(sheets, diameter, circumference) {
    // Default the value of diameter
    diameter = diameter || 3.8;
    circumference = diameter * 3.14159;
    if (circumference > sheets * 10)
        return sheets * 10 / circumference;
    return 1 + wraps(sheets - circumference / 10, diameter + .2);
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "0 => " + w(0)
+ "\n1 => " + w(1)
+ "\n2 => " + w(2)
+ "\n3 => " + w(3)
+ "\n100 => " + w(100)

+ "\n\n0 => " + wraps(0)
+ "\n1 => " + wraps(1)
+ "\n2 => " + wraps(2)
+ "\n3 => " + wraps(3)
+ "\n100 => " + wraps(100);
```

```html
<pre id="text"></pre>
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! If you'd like, you can use JavaScript ES6, and get this to 55 bytes: `w=(s,d=3.8,c=d*3.14159)=>c>s*10?s*10/c:1+w(s-c/10,d+.2)`

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 113 bytes

```c#
double s(int n){double c=0,s=0,t=3.8*3.14159;while(n*10>s+t){s+=t;c++;t=(3.8+c*.2)*3.14159;}return c+(n*10-s)/t;}
```

Ungolfed:

```c#
double MysteryToiletPaper(int sheetNumber) 
    { 
        double fullLoops = 0, sum = 0, nextLoop = 3.8 * 3.14159; 
        
        while (sheetNumber * 10 > sum + nextLoop) 
        { 
            sum += nextLoop; 
            fullLoops++; 
            nextLoop = (3.8 + fullLoops * .2) * 3.14159; 
        } 
        
        return fullLoops + ((sheetNumber * 10 - sum) / nextLoop); 
    }
```

Results:

> for 1 sheet
>
> > 0,837658302760201
>
> for 2 sheets
>
> > 1,64155077524438
>
> for 3 sheets
>
> > 2,41650110749198
>
> for 100 sheets
>
> > 40,8737419532946

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 101 bytes

```
<?$p=pi();$r=3.8;$l=$argv[1]*10;$t=0;while($r*$p<$l){$t+=($l-=$r*$p)>0?1:0;$r+=.2;}echo$t+$l/($r*$p);
```

### Ungolfed

```
<?
$pi = pi();
$radius = 3.8;
$length_left = $argv[1]*10;
$total_rounds = 0;
while ($radius * $pi < $length_left) {
    $total_rounds += ($length_left -= $radius * $pi) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $radius += .2;
}
echo $total_rounds + $length_left/( $radius * $pi );
```

I feel like this could be done a little shorter, but I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>114</s> <s>109</s> 99 bytes

This function tracks the circumference of each layer until the sum of the circumferences is greater than the length of the number of sheets. Once this happens the answer is:

- One less than the number of calculated layers **+** length of leftover sheets **/** circumference of most recent layer

---

```python
def f(n):
    l,s=0,[]
    while sum(s)<n:s+=[.062832*(l+19)];l+=1
    return len(s)-1+(n-sum(s[:-1]))/s[-1]
```

**Update**

- **-10** [16-05-09] Optimized my math-ing
- **-5** [16-05-04] Minimized number of lines

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 44 bytes

```
w=(i,d=19,c=d/15.9155)=>i<c?i/c:1+w(i-c,d+1)
```

I used anatolyg's idea and translated the code into JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, <strike>46</strike> 44 bytes

```
a*0"Gq",:&a9+*\
?\:{$-{1+{&:&+>:{:})
;>{$,+n
```

Expects the number of sheets to be present on the stack at program start.

This uses an approximation of pi of `355/113 = 3.14159292...`, storing `pi/5` in the register. The current iteration's circumference lives on the stack, and `pi/5` is added on each iteration.

**Edit:** Refactored to store the circumference directly - previous version stored `pi/10` and started the diameter as `38`, which was 2 bytes longer.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 79 bytes

```
function p($s,$d=3.8){$c=$d*pi();return $c>$s*10?$s*10/$c:1+p($s-$c/10,$d+.2);}
```

[Run code in Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32c2ee9afe2c688d8541a02ad121e7c9ff757ee5)

I have pretty much only translated Ross Bradbury's answer for JavaScript into a PHP function, which is also recursive.

Comment: Please don't just copy another answer into another language.