# Zig-zag strings

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, string

## Zig-zag strings

Given a string and a positive integer, output the string in a zig-zag wave pattern with a peak amplitude and character spacing equal to the integer.

This is similar to this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35257) but also includes character spacing.

### Input

Input can be read from STDIN or taken as function arguments. Input is a string without newlines and a positive integer.

### Output

Expected output is the string transformed into a zig-zag wave pattern -- starting upwards -- with the first character on the base line. The wave patter must have an amplitude and **character spacing** equal to the integer.

### Examples

*Input*

```
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
2
```

*Output*

```
    o               g                s               
  r   g           n                e               e   G
P       r       i       P        l       &       d       o  
          a   m           u    z               o           l
            m                z               C               f
```

*Input*

```
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
1
```

*Output*

```
 r   a   n   u   e       e   l
P o r m i g P z l s & C d   o f
   g   m       z       o   G
```

This is code golf -- shortest program wins.

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35257/8478)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [the challenge Martin mentioned](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35257/8478), since this challenge has a varying wave size, slightly different rules for making waves, and does not require printing the program's language.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate either.

Comment: I also do not think this is a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>133</s> <s>132</s> <s>136</s> 134 bytes

```
(s,n,o=Array(2*n+1).fill``)=>[...s].map((v,i)=>o=o.map((w,a)=>w+(a-((j=(i+3*n)%(4*n))>2*n?4*n-j:j)?" ":v)+" ".repeat(n-1)))&&o.join`
`
```

Defines an anonymous function. To call it, add `f=` to the beginning to call the function `f`. Then, it can be tested with `console.log(f("Programming Puzzles & Code Golf", 2))`

Thanks to @vihan and @edc65 for helping save some bytes! :)

@kvill: The code has been modified to address the variable character spacing requirement in the spec. Didn't notice that at first!

Comment: Instead of join and split, you can use `keys` or `fill`

Comment: Well done, can be 118: `(s,n,o=Array(2*n+1).fill'')=>[...s].map((v,i)=>o=o.map((w,a)=>a-((j=(i+3*n)%(4*n))>2*n?4*n-j:j)?w+" ":w+v))&&o.join''` (fill and join using template string with no brackets)

Comment: This does not fulfill the specs - character spacing must vary with the size of the integer. See examples.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 151

Here is my answer using Python 2:

```
s,n=input()
a=2*n+1
l,j,o=['',]*a,n,1
for c in s:
 for k in range(a):l[k]+=c+(n-1)*' ' if j==k else' '*n
 j-=o
 if j in [0,2*n]:o=-o
print'\n'.join(l)
```

Sample output:

```
         t                                   e                                   h                                   t                                   e  
      s     i                             v     ,                             t     e                             s     i                             v     
   e           n                       a                                                                       e           n                       a        
t                 g                 w                 t                 g                 w                 t                 g                 w           
                                                         e           n                       a                                                              
                        t     e                             s     i                             v     ,                             t     e                 
                           h                                   t                                   e                                   h
```

and

```
 r   a   n   u   e       e   l 
P o r m i g P z l s & C d   o f
   g   m       z       o   G
```

Comment: This does not fulfill the specs - character spacing must vary with the size of the integer. See examples.

Comment: updated to include character spacing

Answer (score 0):

## J, 75 bytes

```
f=:4 :0
|:((]*>:@i.@#)((+:<:b)|i.#y){x|.}:(],}.@|.)|.=/~i.b=.>:+:x){' ',y
)
```

Here is function in use

```
   7 f'code golf is awesome and I like it'

       l                          
      o f                         
     g                           t
          i                     i 
   e       s                      
  d                           e   
 o           a               k    
c             w             i     
               e           l      
                s                 
                 o       I        
                  m               
                   e   d          
                      n           
                     a
```

Comment: Nice, but this does not fulfill the specs - character spacing must vary with the size of the integer. See examples.